# Tips for golfing in C

Tags: code-golf, tips, c

What general tips do you have for golfing in C? I'm looking for ideas that can be applied to code golf problems in general that are at least somewhat specific to C (e.g. "remove comments" is not an answer). Please post one tip per answer. Also, please include if your tip applies to C89 and/or C99 and if it only works on certain compilers.

Comment: I think the biggest single-sentence hint is: Read the winning codes submitted to IOCCC.

Answer (score 129):

Use bitwise XOR to check for inequality between integers:

`if(a^b)` instead of `if(a!=b)` saves 1 character.

Comment: `a-b` gives you the same effect.

Comment: Similarly you can use `a*b` instead of `a&&b` (has different precendence, may or may not be bad). If you know a /= -b (e.g. they are unsigned) then `a||b` == `a+b`

Comment: better yet combine it with the Elvis Operator `?:` (instead of if) : for exemple to just do something if differents:  `a^b?_diff_:;`

Comment: @OlivierDulac Is there a compiler that accepts an empty ternary if false branch?

Comment: @OlivierDulac You can check. From what I know, GCC has a `?:` operator which is just equivalent to `a ? a : b`

Answer (score 94):

- Abuse `main`'s argument list to declare one or more integer variables:

  ```
  main(a){for(;++a<28;)putchar(95+a);}
  ```

  *(answer to [The alphabet in programming languages](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2078/the-alphabet-in-programming-languages/2093#2093))*

  This solution also abuses the fact that `a` (a.k.a. `argc`) starts out as `1`, provided the program is called with no arguments.
- Use global variables to initialize things to zero:

  ```
  t[52],i;main(c){for(;i<52;)(c=getchar())<11?i+=26:t[i+c-97]++;
  for(i=27;--i&&t[i-1]==t[i+25];);puts(i?"false":"true");}
  ```

  *(answer to [Anagram Code Golf!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1294/anagram-code-golf/1307#1307))*

Comment: There are no data types defined for variables, no return type of main function. Is this valid C syntax?

Comment: @Pavitra : yes, this is commonly known as the ["pre-ANSI" or "K&R"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#K&R_C) C variant. A variable without a type declared explicitly is an `int`. This has since been deprecated and all variables and functions are required to be declared with a type.

Answer (score 78):

## Avoid catastrophic function-argument type declarations

If you're declaring a function where all five arguments are `int`s, then life is good. you can simply write

```
f(a,b,c,d,e){
```

But suppose `d` needs to be a `char`, or even an `int*`. Then you're screwed! If one parameter is preceded by a type, all of them must be:

```
f(int a,int b,int c,int*d,int e){
```

But wait! There is a way around this disastrous explosion of useless characters. It goes like this:

```
f(a,b,c,d,e) int *d; {
```

This even saves on a standard `main` declaration if you need to use the command-line arguments:

```
main(c,v)char**v;{
```

is two bytes shorter than

```
main(int c,char**v){
```

I was surprised to discover this, as I have not so far encountered it on PPCG.

Comment: Why on Earth does that work??

Comment: Apparently this is called K&R style and it precedes ANSI C by a decade.

Comment: Note that using K&R features and newer (say '99) features together nay or may not be possible. Depends on your compiler.

Comment: @dmckee is right. C99 does not allow implicit int, so you have to use `-std=gnu99` and now you're not portable. In clc-speak, you're not even writing "C" code per se, but "Gnu99-C". 'Round here we mostly ignore that, but it's good to mention it if you post code that is compiler-specific. Sometimes people actually *do* download and execute these programs of ours. :)

Comment: @luserdroog: You can use `-std=c89` to tell gcc or clang to compile your code according to that older standard, which does allow implicit int with only a warning.

Comment: Quite often I've found that `main(char*s,int**a)` is the shortest declaration. `s=*++a` will still work as expected, as `sizeof(int*) == sizeof(char*)`.

Comment: @primo In a conforming program, you are not allowed to change the type of the parameters of main(). You may rename them or use a typedef'd type, but you can't change them. `main(char*s,int**a)` is a wildly non-portable gcc extension. But on the other hand, K&R style parameters are just as non-portable and no longer standard C.

Answer (score 76):

The comma operator can be used to execute multiple expressions in a single block while avoiding braces:

```
main(){                                                                                     

int i = 0;                                                                                  
int j = 1;                                                                                  
if(1)                                                                                       
    i=j,j+=1,printf("%d %d\n",i,j); // multiple statements are all executed                                                  
else                                                                                        
    printf("failed\n");                                                                     

}
```

Outputs: `1 2`

Comment: Doesn't work if one of the statements is `break`.

Comment: @MaxLawnboy because `break` is a statement, and this answer is talking about expressions.

Answer (score 47):

Instead of >= and <= you can simply use integer division (/) when the compared values are above zero, which saves one character. For example:

```
putchar(c/32&&126/c?c:46); //Prints the character, but if it is unprintable print "."
```

Which is of course still shrinkable, using for example just > and ^ (a smart way to avoid writing && or || in some cases).

```
putchar(c>31^c>126?c:46);
```

The integer division trick is for example useful to decide whether a number is less than 100, as this saves a character:

```
a<100 vs 99/a
```

This is also good in cases when higher precedence is needed.

Comment: You can write `putchar(c>31&c<127?c:46);`

Answer (score 46):

Certain compilers, such as GCC, allow you to omit basic `#include`s, param, and return types for `main`.

The following is a valid C89 and C99 program that compiles (with warnings) with GCC:

```
main(i) { printf("%d", i); }
```

Notice that the `#include` for stdio.h is missing, the return type for `main` is missing, and the type declaration for `i` is missing.

Comment: Technically it's not valid according to standards as main accepts zero or two parameters, not one. Not that anyone cares in code golf.

Comment: Calling `printf()` (or any variadic function) without a prototype causes _undefined behaviour_. GCC does not compile standard C by default. If you invoke gcc in C89 mode (`gcc -ansi -pedantic`) or C99 mode (`gcc -std=c99 -pedantic`), you will get quite a few complaints, at least in the latter case.

Comment: @NisseEngström: the calling conventions on mainstream C implementations make it safe to call variadic functions without prototypes.  So most C implementations do define the behaviour.

Answer (score 45):

## Use lambdas (unportable)

Instead of

```
f(int*a,int*b){return*a>*b?1:-1;}
...
qsort(a,b,4,f);
```

or (gcc only)

```
qsort(a,b,4,({int L(int*a,int*b){a=*a>*b?1:-1;}L;}));
```

or (clang with blocks support)

```
qsort_b(a,b,4,^(const void*a,const void*b){return*(int*)a>*(int*)b?1:-1;});
```

try something like

```
qsort(a,b,4,"\x8b\7+\6\xc3");
```

...where the string literal contains the machine language instructions of your "lambda" function (conforming to all platform ABI requirements).

This works in environments in which string constants are marked executable. By default this is true in Linux and OSX but not Windows.

One silly way to learn to write your own "lambda" functions is to write the function in C, compile it, inspect it with something like `objdump -D` and copy the corresponding hex code into a string. For example,

```
int f(int*a, int*b){return *a-*b;}
```

...when compiled with `gcc -Os -c` for a Linux x86_64 target generates something like

```
0:   8b 07                   mov    (%rdi),%eax
2:   2b 06                   sub    (%rsi),%eax
4:   c3                      retq
```

[MD XF](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61563/md-xf) wrote a bash [script](https://gist.github.com/aaronryank/c6fd96d543658b19ed9268a3844d0657) that may assist in the writing of simple "lambda" functions.

Edit: This technique was previously published by Shinichiro Hamaji in [this document](http://shinh.skr.jp/dat_dir/golf_prosym.pdf).

## GNU CC `goto`:

You can call these "lambda functions" directly but if the code you're calling doesn't take parameters and isn't going to return, you can use `goto` to save a few bytes. So instead of

```
((int(*)())L"ﻫ")();
```

or (if your environment doesn't have Arabic glyphs)

```
((int(*)())L"\xfeeb")();
```

Try

```
goto*&L"ﻫ";
```

or

```
goto*&L"\xfeeb";
```

In this example, `eb fe` is x86 machine language for something like `for(;;);` and is a simple example of something that doesn't take parameters and isn't going to return :-)

It turns out you can `goto` code that returns to a calling parent.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int f(int a){
 if(!a)return 1;
 goto*&L"\xc3c031"; // return 0;
 return 2; // never gets here
}
int main(){
 printf("f(0)=%d f(1)=%d\n",f(0),f(1));
}
```

The above example (might compile and run on Linux with `gcc -O`) is sensitive to the stack layout.

EDIT: Depending on your toolchain, you may have to use the `-zexecstack` (for gcc) or `-Wl,-z,execstack` (for clang) compile flag.

*If it isn't immediately apparent, this answer was mainly written for the lols. I take no responsibility for better or worse golfing or adverse psychological outcomes from reading this.*

Comment: I've just written a [script](https://gist.github.com/aaronryank/c6fd96d543658b19ed9268a3844d0657) to read parts of a C function from standard in and print a C lambda. Might be worth mentioning in your answer, might just be nice for you to see since you taught me to do this in the first place.

Answer (score 40):

The ternary conditional operator `?:` can often be used as a stand in for simple `if`--`else` statements at considerable savings.

Unlike [the c++ equivalent](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132/tips-for-golfing-in-c/2228#2228) the operator [does not formally yield an lvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1082655/2509), but some compilers (notably gcc) will let you get away with it, which is a nice bonus.

Comment: Addition: If you only need an if, but not an else then the ternary can still be useful.

Comment: `&&` and `||` can also be used: `if(x==3)f()` becomes with your suggestion `x==3?f():0`, and can be further improved to `x==3&&f()`. But be careful with operator precedence - if `f()` is replaced with `y=1`, then the `&&` solution requires an extra set of parenthesis.

Comment: I'd never realized that gcc's `?:` yields an lvalue.  Can I use that in production code?  lol

Comment: @ugoren: `x==3&&f()` can be further golfed to `x^3||f()`

Comment: @fgrieu, yes, though it's not exactly the topic here ([this answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2240/3544) suggests it).

Answer (score 35):

http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Bits are nice.

```
~-x = x - 1
-~x = x + 1
```

But with different precedences, and don't change x like ++ and --. Also you can use this in really specific cases: ~9 is shorter than -10.

```
if(!(x&y)) x | y == x ^ y == x + y
if(!(~x&y)) x ^ y == x - y
```

That's more esoteric, but I've had occassion to use it.
If you don't care about short-circuiting

```
x*y == x && y
if(x!=-y) x+y == x || y
```

Also:

```
if(x>0 && y>0) x/y == x>=y
```

Comment: The last tip (`(x/y) == (x>=y)`) is really useful.

Comment: Some of these don't work on my machine (I guess because these hacks largely rely on "undefined" behavior)

Answer (score 31):

Define parameters instead of variables.

`f(x){int y=x+1;...}`

`f(x,y){y=x+1;...}`

You don't need to actually pass the second parameter.

Also, you can use operator precedence to save parenthesis.
For example, `(x+y)*2` can become `x+y<<1`.

Comment: Or just `x+y*2`, saving yet another char.

Comment: @B1KMusic, `x+y*2` isn't the same, due to operator precedence.

Comment: Right, lol. That would be x+(y*2). I was fixated on the `x+y<<1` example, assuming it was being evaluated as `x+(y<<1)`, and suggested the `*2` instead. I didn't know bitshift operations were evaluated as e.g. `(x+y)<<2`

Answer (score 28):

Use *cursors* instead of pointers. Snag the `brk()` at the beginning and use it as a *base-pointer*.

```
char*m=brk();
```

Then make a #define for memory access.

```
#define M [m]
```

`M` becomes a postfix `*` applied to integers. (The old a[x] == x[a] trick.)

But, there's more! Then you can have pointer args and returns in functions that are shorter than macros (especially if you abbreviate 'return'):

```
f(x){return x M;} //implicit ints, but they work like pointers
#define f(x) (x M)
```

To make a cursor from a pointer, you subtract the base-pointer, yielding a ptrdiff_t, which truncates into an int, losses is yer biz.

```
int p = sbrk(sizeof(whatever)) - m;
strcpy(m+p, "hello world");
```

This technique is used in my answer to [Write an interpreter for the untyped lambda calculus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/284/write-an-interpreter-for-the-untyped-lambda-calculus/3290#3290).

Answer (score 25):

The ternary operator `?:` is unusual in that it has two separate pieces. Because of this, it provides a bit of a loophole to standard operator precedence rules. This can be useful for avoiding parentheses.

Take the following example:

```
if (t()) a = b, b = 0;  /* 15 chars */
```

The usual golfing approach is to replace the `if` with `&&`, but because of the low precedence of the comma operator, you need an extra pair of parentheses:

```
t() && (a = b, b = 0);  /* still 15 chars */
```

The middle section of the ternary operator doesn't need parentheses, though:

```
t() ? a = b, b = 0 : 0;  /* 14 chars */
```

Similar comments apply to array subscripts.

Comment: In this example, `b-=a=b` is even shorter. The `?:` trick is still helpful, `-=` because also has low preference.

Comment: Good point; my example was needlessly complex.

Comment: Another point is that sometimes you want to flip the condition: for `x>0||(y=3)`, `x>0?0:(y=3)` is useless, but `x<1?y=3:0` does the job.

Comment: both clang and gcc allow for an empty _true_ case in the ternary.  If omitted, its value is the value of the condition.  For example, `x>5?:y=1`

Answer (score 24):

Any part of your code that repeats several times is a candidate for replacement with the pre-processor.

```
#define R return
```

is a very common use case if you code involves more than a couple of functions. Other longish keywords like `while`, `double`, `switch`, and `case` are also candidates; as well as anything that is idomatic in your code.

I generally reserve uppercase character for this purpose.

Comment: A shorter replacement would be `-DR=return`. Note that if you include certain characters, it may become necessary to have single or double quotes around the define `-DP='puts("hello")'`.

Answer (score 23):

Since usually `EOF == -1`, use the bitwise NOT operator to check for EOF: `while(~(c=getchar()))` or `while(c=getchar()+1)` and modify value of c at every place

Comment: I don't know C well enough, but wouldn't `while(1+c=getchar())` work?

Comment: @ɐɔıʇǝɥʇuʎs No. The addition operator `+` has higher precedence than the assignment operator `=`, so `1+c=getchar()` is equivalent to `(1+c)=getchar()`, which does not compile because `(1+c)` is not an lvalue.

Answer (score 23):

If you ever need to output a single newline character (`\n`), don't use `putchar(10)`, use `puts("")`.

Answer (score 20):

## Reverse Loops

If you can, try to replace

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){...}
```

with

```
for(int i=n;i--;){...}
```

Comment: for(;++i<n;){...} is even shorter if u declare i as a function parameter like fn(i)

Answer (score 19):

## Use `for` rather than `while`

Any `while` can be changed into a `for` of the same length:

```
while(*p++)
for(;*p++;)
```

On its own, that's not golf.  But we now have an opportunity to move an immediately-preceding statement into the parens, saving its terminating semicolon.  We might also be able to hoist an expression statement from the end of the loop; if the loop contained two statements, we could also save the braces:

```
a=5;while(*p++){if(p[a])--a;++b;}

for(a=5;*p++;++b)if(p[a])--a;
```

Even `do...while` loops should be replaced with `for` loops. `for(;foo,bar,baz;);` is shorter than `do foo,bar;while(baz);`.

Comment: The `for` loop allows up to two statements this way without braces, where the `while` loop only allows one. You could have avoided the braces in the first example with a comma as follows:
`a=5;while(*p++)if(p[a])--a,++b;`

Answer (score 18):

If your program is reading or writing on one in each step basis always try to use [read](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html) and [write](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/write.html) function instead of [getchar()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/getchar/) and [putchar()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/putchar/).

**Example** ([Reverse stdin and place on stdout](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242/reverse-stdin-and-place-on-stdout/1336#1336))

```
main(_){write(read(0,&_,1)&&main());}
```

Exercise:Use this technique to get a good score [here](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/NOP/).

Comment: What do you mean by *in each step basis* ?

Comment: Casey: I guess they mean if the program is reading something, operates on it, and writes output. In a streaming manner, so to say. As opposed to an approach where all the input has to be read and handled at once.

Comment: Joey is right, I meant the same,sorry I didn't checked my inbox until today.

Comment: That stack manipulation is gorgeous.

Comment: On what ABI and compiler does this work?  It does not work on x86-64 (GCC 8.3).

Comment: the last link is dead

Answer (score 16):

Make use of return values to zero stuff. If you call some function, and that function returns zero under normal conditions, then you can place it in a location where zero is expected. Likewise if you know the function will return non-zero, with the addition of a bang. After all, you don't do proper error handling in a code golf in any case, right?

Examples:

```
close(fd);foo=0;   →  foo=close(fd);    /* saves two bytes */
putchar(c);bar=0;  →  bar=!putchar(c);  /* saves one byte  */
```

Answer (score 13):

### Abuse dark corners of array indexing

[image]

`i[array]` desugars into `*(i+array)`, and since `+` is commutative for `pointer+integer` too, it is equivalent to `*(array+i)` and therefore `array[i]`.

It's not very common to see an array indexing expression `(whatever)[x]` where `whatever` requires wrapping in parens and `x` doesn't, but when you see one, you can swap the two positions and write `x[whatever]` to save two bytes.

[A real golfing example.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163258/78410)

Comment: Another case where I've used this: I had a loop using pointer arithmetic to iterate over `argv` (named `v` for brevity), and I only needed the second character of each `argv` string. The original code used `v[0][2]` for this (the pointer arithmetic moved `v` so `v[0]` was always the current string). Indexing being higher precedence than dereferencing meant `*v[2]` wasn't an option (it would be `(*v)[2]`, which saves nothing), but `2[*v]` worked perfectly and saved two characters while behaving identically to `v[0][2]`.

Answer (score 12):

1. Use `*a` instead of `a[0]` for accessing the first element of an array.
2. Relational operators (`!=`, `>`,  etc.) give `0` or `1`. Use this with arithmetic operators to give different offsets depending on whether the condition is true or false: `a[1+2*(i<3)]` would access `a[1]` if `i >= 3` and `a[3]` otherwise.

Comment: `a[i<3?3:1]` is two characters shorter than `a[1+2*(i<3)]`.

Answer (score 11):

You may look into the IOCCC archives (international obfuscated C code contest).

One notable trick is to #define macros whose expansion has unbalanced braces/parentheses, like

```
#define P printf(
```

Comment: The mismatched parentheses have no value in themselves. The point is to define as much of the repeating pattern as possible. You might want to go further, with `#define P;printf(`.

Comment: How does this shorten byte count? Perhaps provide an example?

Comment: @Cyoce See for example [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153117/73111).

Answer (score 11):

## `dprintf` for conditional printing

As you may know, printing something by a condition can be done with `?:`, `&&` or `||`:

```c
cond&&printf("%d\n",n);
cond||printf("%d\n",n);
cond?:printf("%d\n",n);
```

Another interesting idea is to use `dprintf`, which is the same as `printf` except that it takes an extra argument, specifying the output file descriptor.  It will only output to STDOUT if said argument is equal to 1. This can be abused to potentially save a few bytes over the previously mentioned methods:

```c
x-1||printf("%d\n",n);
dprintf(x,"%d\n",n);
```

Answer (score 10):

#### Assign instead of return.

This is not really standard C, but works with every compiler and CPU that I know of:

```
int sqr(int a){return a*a;}
```

has the same effect as:

```
int sqr(int a){a*=a;}
```

Because the first argument is stored into the same CPU register as the return value.

*Note: As noted in one comment, this is undefined behaviour and not guaranteed to work for every operation. And any compiler optimization will just skip over it.*

#### X-Macros

Another useful feature: X-Macros can help you when you have a list of variables and you need to do some operation which involve all of them:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro

Comment: I quoted this and I was corrected, This is simply not true. It will only work with multiplications and divisions and when optimizations are turned off. This is because both operations happen to put their results in eax which is the common register for return. Parameters are stored either in the stack or ecx or edx. Try it yourself.

Comment: You are right, it's undefined behaviour, it also depends on the compiler and on the architecture, I usually check with gcc on x86 and armv7 before posting any answer using this trick. And of course if you enable optimization, any smart compiler would just delete the unnecessary multiplication.

Comment: I've seen this work with GCC but not others

Comment: @Gaspa79: gcc with `-O0` always chooses to evaluate expressions in the return-value register.  I've looked at x86, ARM, and MIPS at least (on http://gcc.godbolt.org/), and gcc seems to go out of its way to do that at `-O0`.  But remember if you take advantage of this, **the language you're programming in is `gcc -O0`, *not C*, and you should label your answer accordingly, not as C**.  It fails at any optimization level other than `-O0` debug mode, and doesn't work with clang IIRC.

Comment: I answered an SO Q&A about exactly why this works with `gcc -O0`, under what conditions: [Return value in unused parameter when falling off the end of a non-void function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57437831) (I didn't get into the GCC source code to look for that level of detail, but covered why assignment always "works": stores need the source value in a register, so GCC can't ever avoid evaluating into some register.  And it always picks the return-value register.)

Answer (score 9):

Using `asprintf()` saves you the explicit allocating and also measuring the length of a string aka `char*`! 
This isn't maybe too useful for code golfing, but eases the everyday work with a char arrays. There are some more good advises in [21st Century C](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025108.do).

Usage example:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char* foo;
  asprintf(&foo, "%s", argv[1]);
  printf("%s",foo);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

`for(int i=0;i<n;i++){a(i);b(i);}`
can be made shorter a few ways:

`for(int i=0;i<n;){a(i);b(i++);}`
-1 for moving the `++` to the last `i` in the loop

`for(int i=0;i<n;b(i++))a(i);`
-3 more for moving all but one statement into the top and out of the main loop, removing the braces

Comment: Using the comma operator is another way to avoid braces in some cases.

Answer (score 9):

### Go functional!

If you can reduce your problem to simple functions with the same signature and defined as single expressions, then you can do better than `#define r return` and factor-out almost all of the boilerplate for defining a function.

```
#define D(f,...)f(x){return __VA_ARGS__;}
D(f,x+2)
D(g,4*x-4)
D(main,g(4))
```

Program result is its status value returned to the OS or controlling shell or IDE.

Using `__VA_ARGS__` allows you to use the comma operator to introduce sequence points in these *function-expressions*. If this is not needed, the macro can be shorter.

```
#define D(f,b)f(x){return b;}
```

Comment: As an alternative to `__VA_ARGS__`, there's the following GNU extension: `D(f,b...)f(x){return b;}`

Answer (score 8):

1. use `scanf("%*d ");` to read the dummy input. (in case that input is meaningless in further program)
   it is shorter than `scanf("%d",&t);` where you also need to declare the variable t.
2. storing characters in int array is much better than character array. example.

   `s[],t;main(c){for(scanf("%*d ");~(c=getchar());s[t++]=c)putchar(s[t]);}`

Comment: Actually, I use `%*d` not only in Golf because it's also useful in situations where one would, for example, want to skip a newline in `scanf("%[^\n]%*c",str);` :)

Answer (score 8):

Print a character then carriage return, instead of:

```
printf("%c\n",c);
```

or

```
putchar(c);putchar('\n'); // or its ascii value, whatever!
```

simply, declare c as an int and:

```
puts(&c);
```

Comment: It is probably worth pointing out that this depends on a little-endian architecture. If c is a big-endian int, then you'll just get the carriage return. (On the other hand, if c is a char, you might get random garbage after instead of a carriage return.)

Comment: @breadbox yep, you are totally right; I just edited: the last excerpt should use c as an int (which is frequently easy to declare as such).

Comment: Does `puts(&c)` really work? That wouldn't necessarily be null-terminated.

Comment: @EsolangingFruit On little-endian with 32-bit ints, an int **0 ≤ c < 256** is stored as the byte sequence **c 0 0 0**. When interpreter the address of **c** as `char *`, we see a singleton string: the character **c**, followed by a null byte.

Answer (score 8):

### Missing `include`s and return values

As noted in the [very first answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2204/12012), some compilers (notably, GCC anc clang) let you get away with omitting `#include`s for standard library functions.

While that *usually* goes well, it might cause problems in some cases, since the implicit declarations of standard library functions inside the source code will cause the compiler to treat return values as `int`s. For example, the code

```
char*p=getenv("PATH");
```

wont work as expected on a 64-bit platform since `getenv` returns a 64-bit memory address which doesn't fit into an *int*.

In this case, there are at least three ways to use *getenv* without errors.

- Include the header file as follows.

  ```
  #include<stdlib.h>
  char*p=getenv("PATH");
  ```

  This is *the right way*™, but not very golfy; it costs **19** bytes.
- Declare *getenv* with the pointer as follows.

  ```
  char*getenv(),*p=getenv("PATH");
  ```

  This costs **10** bytes.
- Finally, unless your code wouldn't work on 32-bit platforms, compile your code on one of those or with the `-m32` flag (gcc). This costs **0** bytes.

Answer (score 8):

## Swap variables

If you ever need to swap variables, don't use the pattern with an extra variable or that addition-subtraction-method, just do some chained XORing:

```
a^=b^=a^=b;
```

Comment: This is undefined behavior, due to a lack of sequence points in between two modifications of the same object. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958514/sequence-point-xor-swap-on-array-get-wrong-result

Comment: This is incredible. 10+ years of coding C and I've always wondered if there was a way to do this, what a delight to stumble upon tonight

Answer (score 8):

## Try `cpow()` instead of `cos()`

Instead of

```
double y=cos(M_PI*2*x);
```

try something like

```
double y=cpow(-1,x*2);
```

This uses [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula), a little complex analysis and the observation that assigning a complex to a double yields the real part (careful with variadic function calls and other subtleties).

\$\cos 2\pi x+j\sin 2\pi x=e^{j2\pi x}=e^{j\pi 2x}=\left(-1\right)^{2x}\$

This type of trick can be used to reduce

```
double y=cpow(-1,x/2);
```

into

```
double y=cpow(1i,x);
```

because \$\left(-1\right)^\frac{x}{2}=j^\frac{2x}{2}=j^x\$

Edit: Equations now inline \$\LaTeX\$ instead of images.

Answer (score 8):

## Exploit ASLR

On systems with [ASLR (Address Space Layout Randomization)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), the address of a stack variable can be used as a one time pseudorandom number. Instead of something like...

```
srand(time(0));
```

...try something like

```
srand(&x)
```

...where the address of `x` (hopefully on the stack) is unique each time the program is run.

Comment: Hmm... Where have I seen this before? :) +1

Answer (score 7):

### Abuse two's complement

A lot of expressions can be changed by (ab)using two's complement. Take this for example:

```
getchar()+1
```

If you need higher precedence, you can use this:

```
-~getchar()
```

Or, if you're using it as the condition for a loop, this can be used:

```
~getchar()
```

Additionally, instead of subtracting one after another subtraction:

```
a+b-1
```

you can add the bitwise-NOT of the second operand:

```
a+~b
```

This applies similarly to multiplication by 2:

```
2*(a-b)-1
```

can be shortened to:

```
a-b+a+~b
```

Comment: @ceilingcat oh, yeah. That explains why it didn't work in my head. But I wonder why it worked in the ASCII rocket challenge.

Answer (score 6):

### `import` if you have to

As noted in the [very first answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2204/12012), some compilers (notably, GCC and clang) let you get away with omitting `#include`s for standard library functions.

Even if you can't just remove the `#include`, there might be [other ways to avoid it](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96555/12012), but that's not always practical or particularly golfy.

In the remaining cases, you can use `#import<header file>` instead of `#include<header file>` to save a byte. This is a GNU extension and it is considered deprecated, but it works at least in gcc 4.8, gcc 5.1, and clang 3.7.

Answer (score 5):

instead of the printf loop

```
for(i=1;i<12;i++){if(!i%3)printf("\n");printf("%d",i);}
```

just use

```
for(i=1;i<12;i++) printf("%c%d",!(i%3)*10,i);
```

it helps me so much .

---

@SamHocevar 's answer (shorter by 2bytes)

```
for(i=1;i<12;i++) printf("\n%d"+!!(i%3),i);
```

---

Credits to @AbhayAravinda for ripping off three more bytes

```
for(i=1;i++<12;) printf("\n%d"+!!(i%3),i);
```

The incrementer here works as a part of the inspector.

Comment: The second line is incorrect; it will actually print the null characters.

Comment: lol im not pinting them into char array , it is terminal console, and nul character doesnt mean space nor a newline:/

Comment: You can use this: `printf("\n%d"+!!(i%3),i);` which is 2 characters shorter.

Comment: knock off 3 more bytes by changing `for` to `for(i=1;i++<12;)`

Comment: Hey sorry. It removes 3 bytes but adds 2. So effectively removes 1 byte

Comment: @NoShady420: That changes behavior, as the value of `i` used in both locations in the `printf` will be one higher. You could tweak the initialization/bounds to fix, or you could rely on implementation defined behavior by putting the `++` later `for(i=1;i<12;) printf("\n%d"+!!(i++%3),i);` (this assumes compiler evaluates arguments from right-to-left, and side-effects apply immediately, which is common, put it on the second use of `i` if it's left-to-right argument evaluation order.

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few tips I've used to my advantage. I've shamelessly stolen them from others, so credit to anyone but me:

**Combine assignment with function calls**

Instead of this:

```
r = /* Some random expression */
printf("%d", r);
```

Do this:

```
printf("%d", r = /* Some random expression */);
```

**Initialize multiple variables together (when possible)**

Instead of this:

```
for(i=0,j=0;...;...){ /* ... */ }
```

Do this:

```
for(i=j=0;...;...){ /* ... */ }
```

**Collapse zero/nonzero values**

This is a neat trick I picked up from someone here (don't remember who, sorry). When you have an integer value and you need to collapse it to either 1 or 0, you can use `!!` to do so easily. This is sometimes advantageous for other alternatives like `?:`.

Take this situation:

```
n=2*n+isupper(s[j])?1:0; /* 24 */
```

You could instead do this:

```
n=n*2+!!isupper(s[j]); /* 22 */
```

Another example:

```
r=R+(memcmp(b+6,"---",3)?R:0); /* 30 */
```

Could be rewritten as:

```
r=R+R*!!memcmp(b+6,"---",3)); /* 29 */
```

Comment: maybe `R*-~!!mxxxx`

Answer (score 5):

## Overload functions (unportable)

Instead of declaring multiple functions...

```
d(x){return x*2;}
float r(float x){return 1/sqrt(x);}
...
printf( "%d %f\n", d(2), r(2) );
```

...declare one "function" that does different things depending on return and parameter types.

```
(*f)()=L"\xf33f048d\xc3c0520f"; // global
...
printf( "%d %f\n", f(2), ((float(*)(float))f)(2) );
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7RCoJAEEXf/YrBCGZkLdOCwOoL@gRfZLcpQbdaVxCiX29bE5LoaWbuuZc7Mj5L6dys0rLu1GnXWlVdF5dD8FWa0l4GQWFPD3OyndHQR2n@DLi@lhYMjnOiq2V7N9bbvQcjJqT9MSx6zjJO1ltV9DKTySZNOMyDSltoykojPQKAm/E3I4RzBXMudChAYUrCl6QElP9ZYDLyx4jjNxjRuBD5/hH43FcW/viglch@Ux6IKTngoffp3EtyXZ5bF9fNGw) This works because some ABI's (Linux x86_64, in this example) use separate registers for floating point and integer arguments and return values.

The disassembly of the `(*f)()` "function"...

```
0:       8d 04 3f                lea    (%rdi,%rdi,1),%eax
3:       f3 0f 52 c0             rsqrtss %xmm0,%xmm0
7:       c3                      retq
```

On a x86_64 Linux machine, this function  takes the first integer parameter, doubles it and places the result in `%eax` (char/short/int/long return value). It takes the first floating point parameter, computes a low precision reciprocal square root and places it in `%xmm0` (float/double return value).

Comment: This would be a better answer if you decoded the x86 asm in a comment or something, and also link to a method for turning hand-written asm into strings.  I don't want to go look up an opcode table.  I can see it ends with a `c3` RET (x86 being little-endian), but I can only guess that the other bytes are `lea eax, [rdi+rdi]` and `rsqrtps xmm0,xmm0` (with no Newton iteration?  that's very inaccurate...), because that's what would make sense.

Comment: You can save 1 byte by using `rsqrtps` instead of `ss`.  The default FP environment has FP exceptions masked, so whatever happens in the high elements won't screw up the scalar value in the low element.

Answer (score 5):

## Inline arrays

If you need a **non-int** constant array and just use it once, you can do

```
float f(a){return (float[]){.3,.2,.7}[a];}
```

instead of

```
float z[]={.3,.2,.7};float f(a){return z[a];}
```

to save 3 bytes.

(In this case it can save one more byte since the blank after `return` can be omitted.)

Answer (score 5):

## Inverse flag update

Sometimes a challenge asks to determine a data set's specific boolean property. To avoid the unacceptably long `return` keyword, I often use a flag variable which gets updated in a loop and assign-returned at the end (I will refer to [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106067/73111) for more detail on assign-returning).

When working with such boolean flags and boolean values, to update them I often use either `f&=a|b` or `f*=a|b` to align them with the result of `a|b`. This is equivalent to saying `f = f && (a|b)`.

However, sometimes a flag needs to be inversely updated, meaning `f = f && !(a|b)`. Naively, one would use `f&=!(a|b)` (9 bytes), or -- using fundamental logical equivalences -- one would golf it to `f&=!a&!b` (8 bytes).
For the case of an inverse flag update, though, one might be better off using the binary shift right operator `>>`, as the previous assignment is (when working with boolean values) equivalent to `f>>=!(!a&!b)`, which simply golfs to `f>>=a|b` (7 bytes).

If the flag update in question does not involve parentheses due to negation (as in the previous example), inverse flag updating may still be shorter, as for example `f&=!a|!b` (8 bytes) is equivalent to `f&=!(a&b)` (9 bytes), which is equivalent to `f>>=a&b` (7 bytes).

Inverse flag updating may in certain cases also be used even though the values in question are not boolean (either `0` or `1`).
If only one operand is boolean, bitwise and (`&`) can still be used, as the second operand's bits will all be cleared. When using bitwise or (`|`) or both operands are non-boolean, one should consider using logical and (`&&`) and logical or (`||`) to get a boolean result, even though they are one byte longer.

As a side node, these rules also apply when the expression is side-effect-dependent, meaning `!f()&&!g()` is equivalent to `!(f()||g())` regarding the execution of `g()`, such that even in those cases inverse flag updating can be used.

For testing purposes, I wrote a simple truth table tester ([TIO-link](https://tio.run/##Tc1NDoIwEAXgNT3FgJG0AcW45SeBJpzCDRSLTRQM4ko5O3YcDHbRyZvvJaN2rVLzvDGduj6bMySPsTH9/pIxZroRbpXpuIAXc3Q/AMdVCSkcYiiTo/2CQDBntZwsR8vJViwIC8RiwVUlqUSVVvEmPjRtrQyhpVHZkYdQ21GEoOyQMXXvg21r7m0bSNIMts2p80LghE4UaT91eeXXYtlgrny3pij@q22Wpba55G96/3qCzk1smucP)).

One recent real-world example of this technique in action would be for example my answer to [Detect Rectangular Text](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163974/73111).

Answer (score 5):

## Boolean constant string selection when the selector's true value is guaranteed to be one larger than the second option's length

At its heart, this tip attempts to golf a ternary if of the form `cnd?str_true:string_false` when two conditions are met, namely that both `str_true` and `string_false` are constant strings and `cnd` is either `0` or `strlen(string_false)+1`.

If the above conditions are met, the expression `cnd?"true":"false"` can be golfed* by one byte to `"false\0true"+cnd` (here `cnd == 0 || cnd == 6` always holds); another byte can be shaved off by not escaping the null byte (a compiler dependent feature).

#### The tip in action

For this example, suppose the string selection's criterion is `k%3`'s truthiness, where `k-1` is never divisible by three. In this case the ternary if

```
k%3?"°@°":"_" // 13 bytes
```

can be golfed to:

```
"_\0°@°"+k%3 // 12 bytes
```

Which can be golfed down to eleven bytes if one does not escape the null byte.

#### Application in obfuscation

As the above requirements are rather strict, this tip is most likely not widely applicable. Nonetheless, the shown technique can also be used to potentially obfuscate a program at no further byte cost.

Given `e` as a truly boolean expression -- `(e) == 0 || (e) == 1` holds -- with the proper operator precedence regarding the upcoming factor, the following snippets are interchangeable* at the same byte count -- when not escaping the null byte.

```
e?"lifeless":"lychee"
"lychee\0lifeless"+e*7
```

Bare in mind that this obfuscation is only non-detrimental to the byte count if the second option's string is not longer than eight characters -- since else the factor spans more than one byte.

*: If interpreted as constant strings.

Comment: If the strings to be selected are two or fewer octets in length, you can use wide characters. `L"AB"+p` will return `"A"` if `p==0` and `"B"` if `p==1`.

Answer (score 5):

### Get the length of a string with `puts()` instead of `strlen()`

According to the standard C specification, `puts()` returns a non-negative integer on success. In practice, most C libraries seem to treat `puts(s)` as equivalent to `printf("%s\n", s)`, which returns an integer equal to the number of bytes written.

As a result, the return value of `puts(s)` is equal to `1 + strlen(s)`. If the additional console output can be ignored, this saves a few bytes.

Comment: "a few" in this case is 4.

Answer (score 5):

## Calculating \$\lceil\log_{10}(n)\rceil\$

Especially in challenges where properties of decimal representations are of interest, one needs to find a number's decimal representation's length, or for \$n\in\mathbb{N}^+\$ equivalently, \$\lceil\log_{10}(n)\rceil\$.
In this post, several approaches are presented and discussed.

For a C source file containing approaches (a.1) to (b.3) together with a testing setup, see [TIO](https://tio.run/##dZLLTsMwEEX3/opRpEo2NcRpeZcs4DcAVU4yKVbScWW7BQR8e7EJFQWVRfyIdO6ZyaQ@XtT1Nj@Cu9eA4NY9umtWTKanZ@cXl1fq8Ikd5ds8B65PCgH4snLovbEEfKKgijlesFtO4o1K5mnlDIWWK6lkNmoySYLNPhgb@ImAdk11GOirHa0H@hCc2IGukv2Hnk52dMVJduKttY53pZrRrBuPBeVlEc9lt5NXSe6DDrhECvD8hA4hPFvYaGd01aOPrRkfJHgMwdACqFT7LVbzwcMOiZjDsHYEe7rpL511XcrUTWOC2WD/CrGJ7o@suID7lQ0nUJw/7rQxLL2LIUb3EdMRWZra9pG3bbzGcdSITQr58dWaoELweoPNYyx9v/b/Ct8utaE0CQbfc8hqND0/NtQKuC5BgXVQPFAmZgxSEqWvcBNjVNzH4/f31Tp4nmVCMPid0dtFofjotBECShg1cu@JgRJIQvqHJOivtRrW@feW9ij92H4C).

I wrote this tip based on [this answer of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/192745), searching for a smaller approach than **(a.1)**.
If you know of any other approach possibly shorter in even a specific scenario, feel free to either add your own tip add to the list below.

### (a.1) An expression in `n`, 20 bytes

```
snprintf(0,0,"%d",n)
```

Versatility is a great property of the above approach, when used to determine a number's decimal representation's length, the most direct approach might be the most byte-effective.

`0` is given its correct decimal representation length of 1.

GCC only throws a warning for ignoring `#include <stdio.h>`, otherwise the inclusion would be very byte-heavy at potentially 19+20=39 bytes. If instead of `sprintf(0`, one uses `sprintf(NULL`, the byte count is increased to 23 bytes. If using both, the byte count could jump to 42 bytes.

### (a.2) A function in `n`, 29 bytes

```
a(n){n=snprintf(0,0,"%d",n);}
```

By being a function, this approach's versatility is high; **(a.1)**'s compiler-specifics also apply, when properly `return`ing, the byte count increases to 5+29=34 bytes.

`0` is given its correct decimal representation length of 1.

### (b.1) A function in `n`, requiring another variable, 32 bytes

```
b(n,k){for(k=0;n;k++)n/=10;n=k;}
```

Of all approaches presented, this one has the worst byte count. However, considering potential compiler restrictions discussed in **(a.1)**, it could prove more byte-efficient, since the approach is nearer to the C core.

`0` is given its incorrect decimal representation length of 0. One can make the case for defining \$\lceil-\infty\rceil:=0\$ which would make this approach closer to a logarithm implementation, when further defining \$\log(0):=-\infty\$.

Modification to calculate \$\lceil\log_b(n)\rceil\$ for a base \$b\in\mathbb{N}^+\$ is possible, changing the byte count by the bytes required to represent \$b\$ in C-source.

### (b.2) A statement requiring existence of two variables, setting `n=0`, 20 bytes

```
for(k=0;n;k++)n/=10;
```

If another variable is already declared and `n` can be either discarded or needs to be cleared regardless and the use case is a whole block instead of a one-line expression, the above could be used. Since it is equivalent in byte count to **(a.1)**, the behavioural differences have to be analyzed.

Minimally wrapped inside a function, it becomes **(b.1)**, both being similar in features.

### (b.3) A statement working additively on `k`, setting `n=0`, 17 (pot. 16) bytes

```
for(;n;k++)n/=10;
```

Another variation on **(b.1)**, removing initialization of `k`. Furthermore, `for(;` leaves space for an expression, potentially allowing to save a semicolon's byte, effectively rendering this approach 16 bytes long.

### (c.1) A statement in `n`, producing `stdout`-output, 14 bytes

```
printf("%d",n)
```

Courtesy of [H.PWiz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71256/h-pwiz).

This approach's utter conciseness and simplicity may be alluring, its major drawback, however, is its `stdout`-output; tolerability being heavily challenge-dependent.

### (c.2) A statement in `n`, producing `stderr`-output, 17 bytes

```
dprintf(2,"%d",n)
```

Courtesy of [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king).

The above is equivalent to the five bytes longer `fprintf(stderr,"%d",n)` and a variant of **(c.1)**, side-effecting not `stdout` but rather the much more clutterable `stderr`.
Ref. `man dprintf.3`

Answer (score 5):

Use bitwise operators to convert characters to uppercase/lowercase. Bitwise AND with 95 (or `'_'`) to convert to uppercase, bitwise OR with 32 (or `' '`) to convert to lowercase, and to invert case, bitwise XOR with 32 (or `' '`).

This only works for letters, and it also seems to work for just a few other characters: `{` and `}` are lowercase for `[` and `]`, `~` and `` ` `` are lowercase for `^` and `@`, `)` is lowercase for a tab, and `*` is lowercase for a newline.

[Example](https://tio.run/##rZHBSsQwEIbvfYqhgqRbFZviQXb1pOAhUPDiQVeoaWoHYlLSrgvKPntNXNNNhd72EAYmH//Px/Dzd86H4QQVl5tKwKrrK9QXzW00WUl8c7sIVQ8fJSqSwHcEwJvSQNeb54yu4QbiRkipt9rIKl7678WmbYXhZScqi/DSEpxk9Aw6/BK6Jg5KEofX2gBxDWjBy6UdK8ionWm6rwNYkCAtBUws6fpxDadwfeVSdva1xsbUAfub/7eNX1S87zNCTJlRiXqjB8FksS0MC41QfQrTH8dnzPI21Mm8Qk7/yXhwXiUgRpF8FLlnrHgqHtldIGKPdcTTBGleJp@ROaDzOhNmNww/).

Answer (score 4):

Knowing basic logical equalities might be able to save a couple bytes. For instance, instead of `if (!(a&&b)){}` try instead using DeMorgan's law `if (!a||!b){}`. The same applies to bitwise functions: instead of `~(a|b)` do `~a&~b`.

Comment: Cf. [De Morgan's laws](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/deMorgansLaws.html).

Answer (score 4):

#### Use `s[i]` instead of `i<strlen(s)` in string-handling loops

For example:

```
for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)s[i]=s[i+1];
```

can be shortened to:

```
for(i=0;s[i];i++)s[i]=s[i+1];
```

Comment: Though in this case one would most likely not bother with indices and use pointer incrementation; `for(;*s;)*s=*++s;`.

Answer (score 4):

## Set an array of `int` to the same value (C99, Linux, BSD, OSX)

Instead of

```
int a[n]=...,x=...;
for(int i=n;i--;)a[i]=x
```

Try something like

```
int a[n]=...,x=...;
wmemset(a,x,n);
```

On MSVC on Windows, `wmemset()` works on arrays of `short` instead of `int`.

Comment: Iirc `wchar_t` is 32 bits wide with gcc on Windows as well, unless you specify the `-fshort-wchar` flag.

Answer (score 4):

**When your algorithm produces output in reverse order, take a pointer to the *end* of a buffer** and write it in decreasing order, returning a pointer to the first element.  It's up to the caller to supply a buffer large enough for any this input, or for any possible input.

[Base conversion / int-to-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166064/how-do-i-print-an-integer-in-assembly-level-programming-without-printf-from-the/46301894#46301894) is a classic example where this interface is used in real life, such as [glibc's internal `_itoa`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/generic/_itoa.h.html#39), used by the printf family of functions as well as some other internal callers.  The max buffer size is 65 bytes for a 64-bit integer -> base 2 string.

```
// takes a pointer to one-past-the-end, which is also a valid option.
char *itoa_end(unsigned long val, char *p_end) {
  // does *not* zero terminate the buffer.  Use *--p_end = 0;
  const unsigned base = 10;
  char *p = p_end;
  do {
    *--p = (val % base) + '0';
    val /= base;
  } while(val);                  // runs at least once to print '0' for val=0.    

  // write(1, p,  p_end-p);
  return p;  // let the caller know where the leading digit is
}
```

---

For golfing, **it can be more compact to take the pointer by reference and modify it, instead of returning it**.  (`return` is a long keyword, and code depending on `gcc -O0` evaluating expressions in the return-value register isn't even C.)

For example, I used this in [ASCII art uncompression from a base-n number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/166708/ascii-art-uncompression-from-a-base-n-number/166831#166831) (i.e. int->string with a digit lookup table), where I already needed a `char*` arg, so it was *very* cheap to declare another as a `char **`.

**Use `*p` everywhere you have `p` in the simple version**.  `*--*p` decrements the caller's pointer, then dereferences that to reference the actual character.

```
/* int n = the number
 * int B = size of I = base
 * char I[] = input table
 * char **O = input/output arg passed by ref:
 *    on entry: pointer to the last byte of output buffer.
 *    on exit:  pointer to the first byte of the 0-terminated string in output buffer
 */
void semi_golfed_g(n,I,B,O)char*I,**O;
{
    for(**O=0 ; n ; n/=B)
        *--*O = I[n%B];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Abuse `wchar_t` to print one character from a string

In a little-endian architecture, you can replace

```
putchar("string"[i])
```

with

```
printf(L"string"+i)
```

to save a byte.

Comment: With `puts` being even shorter replacement for `printf` if adding a newline is okay/desired.

Answer (score 3):

Use bitwise and (&) when comparing boolean expressions to save one byte.

Example:

```
if(i^2&k/3) DoSomething;
```

Really, really useful when combined with the other tips

Comment: The example `if(i^2&k/3)` seems like it would be equivalent to `if(i != 2 && k >= 3)`, but it's not because `&` has higher precedence than `^`. Also, even `if(i-2&k/3)` wouldn't work, because a bitwise and of two nonzero values could result in zero. On the other hand, `if(i!=2&k>2)` would work.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever a certain function is called several times, it's common to `#define` it to something shorter. However, certain compilers (MinGW and clang as far as I know) allows for something even more compact by using function pointers:

```
(*P)()=printf;
P("Test: %d\n", 10);
```

Other compilers might require an `#include` of the proper header file for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

## Favor recursion over loops, especially if going forwards then backwards

### Loops, 67 bytes

```c
l;f(char*s){for(l=0;s[l];)putchar(s[l++]);for(;l;)putchar(s[--l]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYxNCsIwEIWvIlllGoa6H3oSzSIOVAtjLMm4kp69ZorQ4u697/0w3pnXvudHKp3S6DdR4TO@itehUoMwv9Ww7zQEIEuo4pEjKtCyyt9ehjPVi8S92VwI8fchR44o0T6eacq@zb1zQKe5TFmbvmZzTaQbO6t9AQ)

### Recursion, 47 bytes

```c
f(char*s){*s?putchar(*s),f(s+1),putchar(*s):0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NIzkjsUirWLNaq9i@oLQExNMAcnXSNIq1DTV1kISsDKxr/@cmZuZpaFanaSgpaVorFBRl5pUA2TF5IB6QkZiUDGTV/gcA)

You can remove two for-loops and a counter variable. Even if you use just one for-loop in order to loop in one direction, you could save ~10 bytes with this transformation.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you can use *floating point* where you don't expect to.

Ignoring possible *floating point* imprecision issues you still can use them with many operators you wouldn't normally expect :

- `++` `--` increment / decrement
- `!` `||` `&&` Boolean comparative
- `?` and even ternary!

Answer (score 2):

For scanning a string into an array, you can use

```
gets(str);
```

instead of

```
scanf("%s",str);
```

Comment: Yeah, except you should never use `gets`.

Comment: @MDXF Welcome to code golf

Comment: @MDXF: ... for the exact same reason you should never use `"%s"` instead of `"%256s"` as your scanf format string.  (Or whatever the buffer size is.)

Comment: Bonus points if the buffer is smaller than the input and the code relies on overflowing it.

Answer (score 2):

When you have to walk a string you can walk the pointer instead of incrementing the index.

Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

// print each char
void f(char* s) {
    for (int i=0;s[i];i++) putchar(s[i]);
}

// same output than f;
void g(char* s)
{
    for (;*s;) putchar(*s++);
}

int main(void) {
    f("hello\n");
    g("hello\n");
    return 0;
}
```

example: [Remove duplicated & switched case](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85520/15214)

Answer (score 2):

#### Use `#define` instead of functions when possible

For example:

```
f(int i,char*s){/*do something with i and s*/;}
```

Using `#define` can eliminate the argument list type, curly-braces and closing semicolon:

```
#define f(i,s)/*do something with i and s*/
```

Answer (score 2):

## Use bitwise operators for boolean conditions

For example:

```c
if(a||b) /* do something */
```

This saves one byte:

```c
if(a|b) /* do something */
```

Respectively, `a!=b` becomes `a^b` and `a&&b` becomes `a&b`

[An example of using this trick.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243608/108879)

Note that sometimes you have to use `||`. For example:

```
if(!a)b++
```

can be written as

```
a||b++
```

but

```
a|b++
```

doesn't work.

Comment: It's not always true.
For example if I have this if:
if(!a)b++;
I can write: a||b++. And in this case, a|b++ doesn't work

Comment: This trick works in most C-like languages

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, albeit rarely, if your code contains many `for` loops, `#define F for(` may save a byte or two (especially if some of the loops have an empty init section).

If it is applicable to your situation, `#define F;for(` may save even more bytes.

**Examples:**

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153117/61405

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149629/61405

Answer (score 1):

Use recursion over loops.

Recursive example

```
f(){printf("infiniteloop");f();}
```

For loop equivalent is 3 bytes longer.

```
f(){for(;;)printf("infiniteloop");}
```

Comment: I think you are missing a semicolon in your recursive example.

Comment: Do you have an example for a terminating program which could be golfed in this way? Or does this tip only apply to infinite loops?

Comment: Yes, I actually have the shortest c solution in this [example](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/168221/randomizing-until-0/168254#168254)

Comment: `f(){f(printf("infiniteloop"));}` would save a further byte in this example. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NQ7M6TaOgKDOvJE1DKTMvLTMvsyQ1Jz@/QElT07r2f25iZh5YCYgDAA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## Conditional `printf` different format

```
x>0?printf("%c",x):printf("%d",-x);
printf(x>0?"%c":"%.f",x,0.-x);     // float goes different registers
```

Used [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/262438/)

Comment: from the manual: _If the precision is given as just '.', the precision is taken to be zero._

Answer (score 1):

## **Use strings as arrays**

Suppose you had an array like the following.

```c
c[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
// ...some code here...
printf("%d",c[i]);
```

You can make this at least 9 bytes shorter using this method.

```c
char*x,*c="abcdefghij"; // initialize like this if you already have a 'char *' declaration somewhere.
c[]=L"abcdefghij";      // initialize like this you do not (thanks to @ceilingcat for teaching me this one).
// ...some code here...
printf("%d",c[i]-97);
```

---

You can also do something similar with an array of strings.

```c
char*c[]={"cat","dog","mouse","fish"};
// ...some code here...
puts(c[i]);
```

you can reduce 2 bytes. However, this is slightly more tricker to get right. This usually only works when the length of the strings in the array only differ by 2 at most.

The '.' characters are padding that allows you to access each "substring" within the string using a multiple of a fixed offset.

```c
char*c="cat\0..dog\0..mouse\0fish";
// ...some code here...
puts(c+6*i);
```

If the order of the strings do not matter, it is best to place the longest string at the end as, you may be able to save some bytes worth of padding.

```c
char*c="cat\0.dog\0.fish\0mouse";
// ...some code here...
puts(c+5*i);
```

---

This is a useful trick that I have used to reduce quite a lot of bytes in the following answers.

[`lol` is an ambigram, `dad` isn't](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/248070/lol-is-an-ambigram-dad-isnt/248167#248167)

[Can the chefs go?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/267313/can-the-chefs-go/267368#267368)

Comment: Using a string instead of a list of ints also saves bytes for any number between 10 and 94 (printable ascii range is 32-126) because you can use just one character for those where otherwise you'd need 2 (i.e. 34 becomes `B` because it's the 34th printable ASCII character)

Answer (score 1):

## Omit Array Length

If you don't mind possible undefined behavior, define an array `C[]` (compiler assumes to have one element) and then rely upon the adjacent memory as usable space.

```
C[];main(){...}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/985OtY6NzEzT0OzOi2/SCMzr0Qh09bAOtPG0ABIamtrVjtHZ8baZloXFAHl0jSUVFMUlHRAYprWtbX///9LTstJTC/@r1sOAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Omit `return`

Surprised that only [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106067/) provided a similar situation

Instead of `return x;` in the end, use `g=x;` where `g` is a global variable.

In other situations, it may be more shortened. Refer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/204877/) for more about this.

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24058/112488

Comment: the second link is seems to be broken