# Determine if Strings are equal

Tags: code-golf

Your task is **simple**. Determine if one string equals the other (not address, the value) without the use of equality operators (such as `==`, `===`, or `.equal()`) or inequality (`!=`, `!==`) anything similar for other languages. This means anywhere! You may not use these operators anywhere in the code. You may however, you use toggles such as `!exp` as you're not directly comparing the `exp != with something else`.

In addition, you may not use any functions such as [strcmp](https://www.php.net/strcmp), [strcasecmp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php), etc.

As for comparison operators (`>=`, `<=`, `>`, `<`), they are also **disallowed**. I realize that some answers include this, but I'd really like to see more answers that don't borderline the equality operator.

An example using PHP is shown:

```
<?php

$a = 'string';
$b = 'string';

$tmp = array_unique(array($a, $b));

return -count($tmp) + 2;
```

Simply return true or false (or something that evaluates in the language to true or false like 0 or 1) to indicate if the strings match. The strings should be hardcoded seen in the above example. The strings should not be counted in the golf, so if you declare the variable before hand, don't count the declaration.

Comment: Is it necessary to output the result, or simply write a function to return a bool? If writing a complete program is required, that could make-or-break answers in languages with (relatively) significant boilerplate to create a functioning executable like Java and C# (such is the nature of the beast, but this challenge has little in the way of concrete guidelines, leaving much to interpretation/choice). And how are we to take the strings? Hardcoding, reading from STDIN, pass as command-line arguments?

Comment: Is this [code-golf] or a [popularity-contest]? It can't be both.

Comment: Sorry, I have modified my questions to reflect both comments.

Comment: So inequality is allowed?

Comment: If the strings are to be hardcoded more than once(each) , do i have to count their length?

Comment: You can declare the strings in a variable, (such as $a, $b), and those declarations shouldn't count in your final golf.

Comment: Can I return 0/1 instead of False/True

Comment: @DaveChen You should change the title to identical instead of equal

Comment: is `>`/`<` allowed?

Comment: The function `int strcmp(const char *, const char *)` in C returns 0 if the strings are the same and non-zero otherwise. Is the use of this function allowed?

Comment: I am voting to close this challenge as unclear as it is a [tag:code-golf] question centering around a [non-observable requirement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11197)

Answer (score 34):

## Python <strike>49 45 18 22 15</strike> 14

### ( + 3 if string variables are considered)

```
print{a:0,b:1}[a]
```

<strike>The string should be hard coded at the two occurrences of `a` and one occurrence of `b` surrounded by quotes.</strike>

`a` and `b` should be pre-initialized to the strings.

---

## Python shell, 9

### ( + 3 if string variables are considered)

```
{a:0,b:1}[a]
```

Output in shell

```
>>> a = 'string'
>>> b = 'string'
>>> {a:0,b:1}[a]
1
>>> a = 'string'
>>> b = 'stringgg'
>>> {a:0,b:1}[a]
0
>>> {'string':0,'string':1}['string']
1
>>> {'stringggg':0,'string':1}['stringggg']
0
>>>
```

---

Explanation

Creates a dict(hash table) with the key of first and second string.
If second string is the same, the value of first is replaced by that of second.
Finally, we print the value of first key.

EDIT: OP allowed 0/1 instead of False/True as well as using pre-initialized variables.

Comment: @manatwork Golfscript and perl below use 0/1, can't I use that?

Comment: @manatwork Done

Comment: I am counting 16 instead of 13, for your second solution.

Comment: @Abhijit the `a` and `b` are not to be included, the strings should be hard-coded there, that's why I added + 2*len(str1) + len(str2) + 6 (')

Comment: +1 for clevernesse but this is by far not the shortest anymore ;)

Comment: @avalancha Thanks, I think the upvotes are because this is a python solution and not golfscript, brainf**k or j.

Answer (score 21):

## Python (<s>17</s> 11):

```
b in a in b
```

(Checks if b is contained in a and a is contained in b, if that wasn't clear from the code.)

### Alternative python: (<s>8</s> 7)

derived from Tom Verelst's Go solution:

```
b in[a]
```

Bonus: this works for any type.

EDIT:

Wait a second, just read that you can also directly program in the strings, and don't have to count quotes... (or at least, that what golfscript does). So... Python on par with golfscript? Oh my!

### Alternative alternative Python (<s>5</s> 4):

(thanks  Claudiu)

```
"string"in["string"]
```

original:

```
"string" in["string"]
```

### Alternative Alternative Alternative Bendy-ruly Python (2):

```
"string"is"string"
```

Nothing was said about comparison **keywords** (This is not a serious submission, just something that occurred to me...)

Comment: You could use `b in a in b`. The and a is not necessary...

Comment: Now it is duplicate of [willem's answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/23926).

Comment: You could get it down to seven characters by removing the whitespace between `in` and `[a]`. i.e. `b in[a]` should work.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. Thanks :)

Comment: Impressive! Also didn't know that

Comment: @Synthetica: You can also remove the whitespace: `"string"in["string"]` works.

Comment: @Claudiu Thanks! Didn't realize!

Comment: `"string" in["string"]` also works in Julia, but `"string"in["string"]` does not.

Answer (score 14):

## JavaScript, <strike>11</strike> 10

Strings have to be stored in a and b.

```
!(a>b|a<b)
```

Edit: thanks Danny for pointing out, `|` is enough instead of `||`

Comment: You are using inequality operators.

Comment: No, I am using greater than and less than operators. Those were not forbidden in the contest.

Comment: +1. This is going to work identically in many other languages too.

Comment: I may be wrong but can't you remove one `|`?

Comment: Definitely a rules oversight - comparison *functions* are banned, as are equality and inequality *operators*, but *comparison operators* aren't mentioned.

Comment: -1 for <> - perhaps rules changed after you wrote this solution?

Comment: @philcolbourn Yes, rules changed yesterday but answer is 2 days old.

Answer (score 8):

## Ruby, 11

```
s = 'string'
t = 'string'
!!s[t]&t[s]
```

Checks if each string is contained within the other.

Comment: `!(a<b||b<a)` would be the same...

Comment: except you can't use <>

Answer (score 8):

## Python - 11 (without the strings)

```
>>> a = 'ss'
>>> b = 's'
>>> a in b in a
False
```

Comment: In the same spirit:`a<=b<=a` which is only 7 characters. Although I don't know whether the comparison `<=` would be considered an "inequality". From the question it appears that any comparison that is not an equality check is okay, which would allow `<=`.

Comment: yeah, thats a nice one @Bakuriu, and I agree, its not totally clear when the rules are violated or not. 'in' after all alsoome how contains an equal statement.

Answer (score 6):

### GolfScript (5 chars)

```
'string1''string1'].&,(
```

Fairly straightforward port of the PHP reference implementation. Leaves `0` (=false) on the stack if the strings are the same, or `1` (=true) if they're different.

Comment: doesn't work for me: `1` if the string are the same, and `2` if they're different. `'string1''string1'].&,1&` works

Comment: @guy777, this assumes that the stack is empty at the start. The question is rather vague on program fragments. You're probably testing it as a whole program and starting with an empty string on the stack from stdin.

Answer (score 5):

## C++, <s>63</s> <s>58</s> 56

```cpp
const char* a = "string";
const char* b = "string";
int main(){while(*a**b*!(*a^*b))++a,++b;return!(*a^*b);}
```

Comment: Could you get away with `auto` instead of `const char*`?

Comment: I think so yes, but since the rules say the string variables aren't counted towards the character count I didn't bother to golf them.

Comment: Could you fold increments into the while test and leave the body empty? And if you go for c instead of c++, remove int at the beginning.

Comment: I don't see any way to reduce the character count by folding the increments into the while test without hitting the same bug of accessing a string past the end I pointed out in Abhijit's C answer. You only want to increment a and b if both tests pass (neither a nor b is pointing to the null terminator and a is equal to b). There's probably a way to improve on this but I haven't been able to find it!

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript (45 bytes):

Here is another solution in Javascript.

```php
var a='string',b='string',c=!a.replace(b,'');
```

The space is important.

`c` should be `true`.

Comment: Only `!a.replace(b,'')`  is counted. So character count should be 16. Actually, some people even count it 14, since you can specify the string directly.

Answer (score 3):

## coreutils: uniq -d

Just enter your two strings as the standard input of a pipe and `uniq -d | grep -q .` will print nothing but will have a return value of success or error. If you want to print the boolean, just replace with `uniq -d | grep -c .`

How many characters? I let you count; `uniq -d|grep -q .` with no extra spaces has 17 characters in it, but since the whole job is performed by uniq, I would say this solution is a 0-character one in... `uniq` own language!

Actually, `uniq -d` will print one line if the two strings are identical, and nothing if the are different.

Answer (score 3):

### APL (<s>8</s> 9)

Update: the old one does  not work for strings of different lengths.

```
{∧/∊⌿↑⍺⍵}
```

- `↑⍺⍵`: make a matrix with `⍺` on the first line and `⍵` on the second line, filling blanks with spaces.
- `∊⌿`: For each column, see if the upper row contains the lower row (as in the old version).
- `∧/`: Take the logical `and` of all the values.

Old one:

```
{∧/⍺∊¨⍵}
```

- `⍺∊¨⍵`: for each combination of elements in `⍺` and `⍵`, see if the element from `⍺` contains the element from `⍵`. Since in a string these will all be single characters, and a string contains itself, this is basically comparing each pair of characters.
- `∧/`: take the logical and of all the values (if all the characters match, the strings are equal)

Comment: This [fails on strings that are equal except for trailing spaces](https://tryapl.org/?a=%27ab%27%7B%u2227/%u220A%u233F%u2191%u237A%u2375%7D%27ab%20%27&run).

Answer (score 3):

Strings have to be stored in a and b. Will not work if either is `null`.

## C#, 53

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Replace(b,"")+b.Replace(a,""))
```

---

## C#, 28

```
a.Contains(b)&&b.Contains(a)
```

Answer (score 3):

#### PHP - 49 characters

```
!(strlen($a)^strlen($b)|strlen(trim($a^$b,"\0")))
```

Comment: Couldn't something like this work: `!strlen(str_replace($a,'',$b));` It should return 1 if two strings are equal?

Comment: @D.Kasipovic Interesting, but I think it fails for `$a == 'foo'` and `$b = 'foofoo'` :)

Comment: True, how about this then, it limits replace to one `!strlen(preg_replace("/{$a}/", '', $b, 1));` and is 45 characters?

Comment: I suppose you could use anchors instead, but more importantly it would require preg_quote() as well :)

Answer (score 3):

## Python - 12

```
not({a}-{b})
```

This solution uses sets. Subtracting equal sets will result in an empty set, which has a boolean value of False. Negating that will result in a True value for a and b being equal strings.

```
>>> a="string1"
>>> b="string2"
>>> not({a}-{b})
False

>>> a="string"
>>> b="string"
>>> not({a}-{b})
True
```

Edit: Thanks to Peter Taylor for pointing out the unnecessary whitespace.

Comment: What output does this give for `a="s", b="ss"`?

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Since `"s"!="ss"`, it will output `False`. Case sensitivity is also preserved. It even works for `a="", b="s"`. The code does not convert strings to sets, but creates sets containing the strings.

Comment: Ah, `{}` isn't the same as `set()`. You can save 1 char by removing the whitespace.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Thanks for pointing out the unnecessary whitespace. 
`{a}` is equivalent to `set([a])`.

Comment: How about `not {a}-{b}`?

Answer (score 3):

### C — 62

```
e(char*p,char*q){for(;*p&*q&&!(*p^*q);q++,p++);return!(*p^*q);}
```

Tested. Call as `e(str1, str2)`

Come to think of it, if you don't count the `char*p,char*q`, which seems only fair, it's only 49 bytes :)

Comment: Welcome to the site! For code-golf challenges, we encourage you to trim as many bytes from your code as you can, and post the byte count in your answer header.  Check out the [Tips for Golfing in C](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2203/tips-for-golfing-in-c) thread for some good ideas.

Comment: You don't really need `np` and `nq`. One loop will do, because if you reach the end of one string before the other they will have a different value.

Comment: Thanks. I realize that. I was working on my shortened version (above). Going back to see if I can shorten it further.

Comment: `*p&*q` may stop the loop too early (e.g. `'0'&'A'==0`)

Comment: @ugoren: If `*p=='0'` & `*q=='A'`, we *want* the loop to stop early, as we know the strings are not equal.

Comment: @Emmet, Right, I was looking at the pieces separately. But then, testing `*p` is enough, you don't need `&*q`.

Comment: What if `p` is longer than `q`? We want it to stop when *either* `p` *or* `q` is pointing at a `NUL` or we might run off the end of the shorter one and segfault.

Comment: Can you move `p++` to the body of the loop?

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica / Wolfram Language, 15 bytes

```
2 - Length[{a} ∪ {b}]
```

Pretty self explanatory, sets each string as a set, then checks the length of the union of the two sets. If the strings are the same, returns 1, otherwise returns 0. If I'm allowed to return '2' for "different" and '1' for "same", subtract two bytes.

Answer (score 2):

### Java - <strike>162</strike> 147 characters

The idea is to compare the difference of each byte, same bytes will have difference 0.
The program will throw `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` for when bytes are different (try to access a negative index) or when strings are of different length. It will catch the exception and return 0 (strings not equal), or return 1 otherwise (strings equal).

**Compressed:**

```
String a = "12345";
String b = "12345";
byte[]x=a.getBytes(),y=b.getBytes();int z,i=a.length()-b.length();try{for(byte d:x){z=d-y[i];z=x[-z*z];i++;}}catch(Exception e){return 0;}return 1;
```

**Normal:**

```
String a = "12345";
String b = "12345";
byte[] byteArrA = a.getBytes();
byte[] byteArrB = b.getBytes();

int byteDifference = 0;
int i = a.length() - b.length();

try {
    for (byte aByte : byteArrA) {
        byteDifference = aByte - byteArrB[i];
        byteDifference = byteArrA[-byteDifference*byteDifference];
        i++;
    }
} catch (Exception e){
    return 0;
}

return 1;
```

Comment: Comparison operators exist in the loop.

Comment: Thank you @hexafraction, I updated answer to not include them.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell -- 9

```
elem a[b]
```

Note that this, just like many entries here, is just an expression. This is not a Haskell program.

Answer (score 2):

## Prolog 7

```
e(A,A).
```

This makes use of the pattern matching feature in Prolog to unify the 2 arguments to the predicate, which effectively tests for equals equivalence *when there is no unbound variable*.

Sample usage:

```
?- e("abcd", "Abcd").
false.

?- e("abcd", "abcd").
true.
```

Technically speaking, the behavior of this solution is that of unification operator [`=/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28%3D%29/2), rather than that of [`==/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=standardorder), which checks for term equivalence. The difference shows when unbound variables are involved. In this solution, when unbound variable is supplied, the predicate will return `true` when unification is successful. In comparison, `==/2` will compare order of term without unification.

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, 68 Bytes

I assume you're prohibited to use **any** comparison operators. So `<` or `>` are included.

The idea is to use bitwise XOR. In different languages this operator has different syntax - I'll show an example for PHP. There it's available with `^`. Unfortunately, its behavior with strings isn't as good as it could be, so you'll need to check string length before. That is because in PHP, xor will strip the longer string down to the length of the shorter string.

Next thing is to work with strings properly, because a single `xor` will not produce a result, available for further operations in PHP. That's why [`unpack()`](http://php.net/unpack) was used. So, the code would be:

```
return !(strlen($a)^strlen($b)) & !array_filter(unpack('c*', $a^$b))
```

It's longer than option with `<` / `>` but it won't use them. Also, the important thing is about [PHP type juggling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) (so empty array will be cast to `false`). Or maybe there's a simpler way to check if an array contain non-zero members (*Edit*: while I've been typing this, there's a good catch with `trim()` in another answer, so we can get rid of array operations)

But I believe there are languages, where we can do just `a ^ b` - literally, getting the result. If it's `0` (treated from all resulted bytes) - then our strings *are equal*. It's very easy and even more simple than `<` or `>` stuff.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP

```
    $string = 'string';
    isset( ${'string'} );
```

This script may not have any utility, but atleast this provides a way to compare strings.

## PHP

Aother one:

```
    $string = 'something';
    $text   = 'something';
    return count( array( $string => 1 , $text => 1 ) ) % 2;
```

Comment: Wow very lovely. And [doing it like this](http://codepad.org/wFUJBDsc) can make it possible to use any string (with spaces and unicode).

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, 21

This one is doing the job using variable indirection.

```
$$a=$b;!!$$b;
```

Or, if you don't need it to be bool

```
$$a=$b;$$b;
```

**EDIT** : I forgot to handle the case where you try to compare two empty strings, so the code now is

```
$$a=$b;!($a.$b)||$$b;
```

which is 21 chars.

Comment: I expected this to give errors when given strings which aren't valid identifiers, but to my surprise it doesn't.

Comment: Two problems: 1. Returns true when comparing "0" and "". 2. Returns true when $b is the name of an existing variable (in the current symbol table) having a value that converts to true (e.g. "GLOBALS" or "_SERVER" in global scope, or "b" in any scope), even when $b is not equal to $a.

Answer (score 2):

### CPython: 6

```
a is b
```

---

```
>>> a = 'string'
>>> b = 'string'
>>> c = 'STRING'
>>> a is b
True
>>> a is c
False
```

The use of `is` is obviously pretty suspect, but since the task specifically calls out that we're to determine value equality rather than reference equality, and `is` only compares object identity, I feel like it *may* not fall under the list of banned operators.

Of course there's also some question as to whether this is even valid; it works on all of my systems, but it's implementation-specific and probably won't always work if the strings aren't defined by hand in the interactive interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

**C 342 golfed**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 100
#define P(x) printf("%s\n",x)
#define G(x) gets(x)
void e(int x){x?P("y"):P("n");}
int main(){
char s[N],t[N];char *p,*q;int r=0; int n=0,m=0;int i=1;p=s,q=t;
if((p=G(s))&&(q=G(t))){while (*p){n+=i*(int)*p;m+=i*(int)*q;i++;p++;q++;if(!(*q)){break;}}
if(!*p&!*q){if(!(m-n)){r=1;}}e(r);}
return 0;
}
```

Note: Visual Studio complains if you don't use their safe methods eg gets_s.
CodeBlocks with mingw compiles without warnings.

**C 655 not golfed**

Code creates weighted sum of chars for each string.
If the difference is zero then they are equal, including 2 empty strings:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#define N 100
#define P(x) printf(x)
#define G(x) gets_s(x)

void e(int x){ x ? P("equal\n") : P("not equal\n"); }
int main()
{
    char s[N], t[N];//words
    char *p = 0, *q = 0;
    int r = 0; //result 0=false
    int n=0, m=0; //weighted sums
    int i = 1; //char pos start at 1
    if ((p=gets_s(s)) &&
        (q=gets_s(t)))
    {
        while (*p)
        {
            n += i*(int)*p;
            m += i*(int)*q;
            i++;
            p++;
            q++;
            if (!(*q)){
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!*p && !*q){ //both same length strings
            if (!(m - n)){ r = 1; } //weighted sums are equal           
        }//else r=0, false=>not equal

        e(r);
    }
    else{
        P("error\n");
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Nice job, but you should probably golf it.

Comment: I can't compile your submission. I get "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_gets_s", referenced from:
      _main in golf-310cf2.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64"

Answer (score 2):

## Python

It's long and it's not beautiful, but this is my first entry!

```
def is_equal(a,b):
    i=0
    a,b=list(a),list(b)
    if len(a)>len(b):
        c=a
        lst=b
    else:
        c=b
        lst=a
    try:
        while i<len(c):
            for j in c:
                if j not in lst[i]:
                    return False
                i+=1
    except IndexError:
        return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 2):

## R (4 chars)

```
'string1'%in%'string2'
```

Or, for an actual function,

### (6 chars)

```
`%in%`
```

which is called with

```
`%in%`(x,y)
```

As R is  a vector-based language, is treated as a string and b is treated as a vector of one string, so this is similar to the `elem a[b]`/`a in b in a`/`a in[b]` solutions in spirit.

Answer (score 1):

## grep 14 characters

Of course, I only count the grep code; the two strings are on two consecutive lines in the input (either a pipe or a file or even an interactive session).

```
$ echo -e 'string\nstring' | grep -cPzo "(?s)^(\N*).\1$"
1
$ echo -e 'string\nstring1' | grep -cPzo "(?s)^(\N*).\1$"
0
$ echo -e 'string1\nstring' | grep -cPzo "(?s)^(\N*).\1$"
0
```

Answer (score 1):

## Matlab: 12 chars (after the strings are in variables)

```
~(x*x'-y*y')
```

The code including assignments would be:

```
x='string1'
y='string2'
~(x*x'-y*y')
```

Answer (score 1):

## The very crazy way

Just for the fun, but many ways for making it fail if one thinks about it. More over, don't forget the strings will be EXECUTED by the shell.

```
$ echo -e 'string\nstring1' | sed -e '1s/^/#define /' | cpp | sh 2>/dev/null && echo true
$ echo -e 'string\nstring' | sed -e '1s/^/#define /' | cpp | sh 2>/dev/null && echo true
true
$ echo -e 'string1\nstring' | sed -e '1s/^/#define /' | cpp | sh 2>/dev/null && echo true
```

A good counter-example is comparing "string" as first string and "rm -Rf /" as a second string; just check as root and see: it will say "true" though both strings obviously aren't the same.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript [18 bytes]

```
(_={})[a]=1,!!_[b]
```

**OR**

```
!!((_={})[a]=_)[b]
```

This will return `true` if `a == b` and `false` if `a =/= b`. The logic behind is creating an object with a value of `a` as a property and returning `1` or `undefined` in case if a property of `b` value exists or doesn't exist in that object.

Comment: The rules say you're allowed to return an object that evaluates to true or false, so the `!!` is not necessary

Comment: @James_pic Yeah, but otherwise it will return `1` or `undefined` (or object/`undefined` for the second case).

Comment: I interpreted the rules as saying that truth-y and false-y values would do in place of true and false, so I'd think that 1 or undefined were good enough.

Comment: @James_pic I just wanted to be on the safe side :) If so, then `18-2 = 16 bytes`.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript [15 bytes]

```
![a].indexOf(b)
```

This will return `true` if `a == b` and `false` if `a =/= b`. The script is looking for the value of `b` in the array that holds a single element of value of `a`.

Answer (score 1):

### C - <s>86</s> 83

```
main(int i,char**v){return*v[1]&!(*v[1]++^*v[2]++)?main(3,v):!(*--v[1]^*--v[2]);}
```

Obvioulsy not the shortest, but this doesn't work with string variables and instead takes the strings as input from the console. Also, I sort of like the recursive main, even if it's obviously not the shortest version. But certainly the least advisable.

Comment: You don't need spaces around many operators. For example, `char** v` can be written as `char**v`. There are some exceptions (like `42 / *pointer`), but in most cases spaces can be safely removed near special characters.

Comment: And an apersand too much. Not on top today.

Answer (score 1):

**Python, 7 chars.**

```
b in[a]
```

Where `b` and `a` are strings.

Comment: You can write this `b in[a]` with one less character.

Answer (score 1):

### C++: 104 <s>105</s> characters

```
#include<string>
#include<set>
template<typename T>
int f(T a,T b){std::set<T>S={a};return S.count(b);}
```

EDIT: Saved a character by making it a template function.

Function itself is 51 characters. Other C++ answers already posted are shorter, but I wanted to try one that wasn't also pure C. In fact, this requires C++11. For earlier versions of C++ you can replace `std::set<T>S={a};` with `std::set<T>S(&a,&a+1);` at the expense of an extra 5 characters.

Answer (score 1):

**Excel VBA**

```
Function stringmatch()
a = ""
b = ""
For i = 1 To Len(a)
If Asc(Right(Left(a, i), 1)) - Asc(Right(Left(b, i), 1)) Or Len(a) - Len(b) Then
debug.print "string unnmatch"
Exit Function
End If
Next
debug.print  "string match"
End Function
```

Comment: I think your `<>` is classified as an inequality operator, which is not permitted by the rules.

Comment: @Ace oh thx, seeing "=" is allowed I thought "<>" is also allowed

Comment: `=` is allowed as an assignment operator. If your language uses this symbol as an equality operator you still cannot use it. (This applies to Visual Basic .NET, I don't know about Excel VBA.)

Comment: Oh ok thanks, I have used another expression (edited code)

Answer (score 1):

### Java (235 characters for golfed version at bottom).

Strings are not hardcoded, but this is a trivial change.

```
   public boolean areEqual(String a, String b) {
    int[] q = new int[1];
    int i = 0;
    try {
        while (true) {
            noOp(q[(int) a.charAt(i) - (int) b.charAt(i)]);
            i++;
        }
    } catch (Error e) {
        try {
            a.charAt(i);
        } catch (Error e2) {
            try {
                b.charAt(i) {catch(Error e3){
                    return true;
                }
                }
            }


            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

public void noOp(int i) {
}
```

Traverses both strings, using the difference in `char`s to select an array index (which is 0-based). No in-loop comparisons or Math.max used. Using `Error` as a throwable instead.

Golfed for use under certain circumstances (instantiated class, used from same package):

```
boolean a(String a,String b){boolean t=true,f=!t;int[]q={1};int i=0;try{while(t){q[(int)a.charAt(i)-(int)b.charAt(i)];i++;}}catch(Error e){try{a.charAt(i);}catch(Error z){try{b.charAt(i){catch(Error g){return t;}}}return f;}return t;}}
```

Comment: Any purpose for `noOp`?

Comment: The golfed and ungolfed code don't compile...

Comment: @ColeJohnson I'm guessing the `noOp` function is because `array[i]` isn't a statement by itself. Rather than calling a function OP could just set the value of that array index since it's not used anyway.

Answer (score 1):

### Groovy  347

```
def compare(str1,str2){
    def str1val = 0
    def str2val = 0

    MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
    md5.digest(str1.getBytes("UTF-8")).each{ str1val += it*2 }
    md5.digest(str2.getBytes("UTF-8")).each{ str2val += it*2 }

    if(!(str1val-str2val)) {
        return true    
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl - 10

```perl
/^\Q$w\E$/
```

The input is in `$_` and `$w`. The output is stored in `$&`.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 4 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit infix function. Requires `⎕IO←0`

```apl
~⍳⍥⍮
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgkG/@se9W5@1Lv0Ue@6/2lAgUe9fRC5ruZD640ftU0E8oKDnIFkiIdn8H/1xCR1hTQFIKWgzqVeXFKUmZcOFoAyAQ)

`⍥⍮` put each argument into a list

`⍳` index of right list's elements in left list (0 if match, 1 if not)

`~` logical NOT

Comment: 5 bytes possible

Comment: @KritixiLithos What was yours?

Comment: `2=` in place of `-1=`

Comment: @KritixiLithos Wouldn't `=` be forbidden? I had `¯1+`.

Comment: Ah, forgot about that

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, 30 bytes

```
param($a,$b)$a-in$b-and$b-in$a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVRRyVJUyVRNzNPJUk3MS8FSAKZif///9dNVPAAqsz/r5sEYQAA)

Takes two string inputs as command line parameters, `-a` and `-b`.

## PowerShell, <s>20</s> 16 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to @mazzy!

```
!($args|gu).Rank
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X1FDJbEovbgmvVRTLygxL/v///9KHkCZfCUFKA0A)

Alternate answer, takes two strings as commandline arguments.

Comment: nice alternative. you can save more [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X1FDJbEovbgmvVRTLygxL/v///9KHkCZfCUFKA0A "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @mazzy thanks, I didn't even know the Rank property existed until now!

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 79

```
a=list(a)
b=list(b)
for i in range(len(a)):
 if ord(a[i])-ord(b[i])<0:
  print 'n'
```

Comment: The question has been edited: the strings should be hard-coded, though I think your approach is better (golfier).

Comment: It will print `n` multiple times

Comment: At the cost of a few chars, I could make it better

Comment: Your program does not return whether the strings are equal or not, although it could be changed trivially to suit the rules.

Answer (score 0):

### Perl, 24 bytes

```perl
$r=!(-1+keys{$a,1,$b,1})
```

The two strings are given in `$a` and `$b`. The result is stored in `$r`.

The trick is using a hash array. If the strings are equal, then only one hash entry is created.

---

A standalone variant that gets the string from STDIN and returns 0, if the strings match and 1 otherwise:

```
$h{<>}=$h{<>}=1;exit -1+keys%h
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python - 52 chars without strings (76 with strings)

The `in` operator might be skirting the edges, but the rules disallow strict equality comparison, not similarity comparison.

```python
a="string"
b="string"
x=a in b and not(len(a)-len(b)>0 or len(a)-len(b)<0)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Python 2 - <del>50</del> 54 (including strings)

Thanks to Ace for way around the "==" issue

```
a='string'
b='string'
not(len(''.join(set(a+b)))-len(a))
```

Output

```
True
```

Non-equal strings

```
a='string'
b='String'
not(len(''.join(set(a+b)))-len(a))
```

Output

```
False
```

Comment: Can't use `==`, even if you're not comparing the strings.

Comment: You may wish to use `not (len(''.join(set(a+b)))-len(a))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 21

[Online version](http://ideone.com/D8kgQ9)

Strings have to be stored in `a` and `b`:

```ruby
!!(a+b=~/^(#{a})\1$/)
```

Checks if the concatenation of `a` and `b` contains `a` twice.

Comment: Insufficient. Gives `true` for `a="string"; b="stringstring"`. You have to anchor the regular expression to the start of string too with `^`.

Comment: I feel like `=~` needs to be forbidden, or you can just do `!!(a=~/^#{b}$/)`

Comment: Well, it's just an abbreviation for `.match(x)`: `!!(a+b).match(/^(#{a})\1$/)` - but yes, it somehow is an equality operator...

Answer (score 0):

### D 30

```
string a="somestring";
string b="somestring";

return !reduce!"a|b"(a[]^b[]);
```

Comment: I think `!reduce!` falls under the banned equality operators.

Comment: it negates the integer result, no different than the C solution using the same xor trick

Answer (score 0):

### Python 15 - 2( if you hard code the string in the solution) = 13

```
>>> s = 'string'
>>> t = 'string'
>>> 1 is len({s,t})
True
>>> s = 'string1'
>>> t = 'string2'
>>> 1 is len({s,t})
False
```

### Python 17

```
>>> s = 'string'
>>> t = 'string'
>>> s in t and t in s
True
>>> s = 'string1'
>>> t = 'string2'
>>> s in t and t in s
False
```

Answer (score 0):

### Perl, 25 bytes

```perl
$r="$a$b"=~/^(\Q$a\E)\1$/
```

The input is expected in variables `$a` and `$b`. The result is stored in `$r`.
It uses a regular expression to check, whether the concatenation `"$a$b"` is a duplicate of `$a`.

Comment: Does that answer allow for "regex-special" charaters in either `$a` or `$b`? (will it still match properly if `$a` contains a `.`?

Comment: @IQAndreas: Yes, the special characters are disabled by `\Q...\E`.

Answer (score 0):

## Python (7)

Assuming strings are stored in variables `a` and `b`:

```
a<=b<=a
```

Answer (score 0):

### Emacs Lisp

```
(split-string-and-unquote a b)
```

returns nil when a == b, something else when a != b

```
(print (if (split-string-and-unquote a b) "not equal..." "equal!"))
```

If I'm doing string work in elisp I use the popular package s.el in which it could be written a little shorter and without a negated output

```
(not (s-split a b t))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Java - 193

```
new int[]{0,1,0}[new BigInteger(a.getBytes()).subtract(new BigInteger(b.getBytes())).signum()+1]
```

No comparison operators at all, not even a `<` or `>`.

Comment: This is just a code snippet. The consensus for challenges on PPCG is that a [full program or function is required](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet) unless explicitly stated in the question. Moreover 1 and 0 are not truthy and falsey in java so I'm not sure this is allowed. Finally you're making use of Java's `BigInteger` but you're not taking the byte count hit for the import of that class.

Answer (score 0):

## C - 45 characters

```
r;main(){ // 9 chars here
    char *a = "str2";
    char *b = "str1";
while(r+=*a^*b,*a++**b++);return!r;} // 36 more here
```

Comment: Fails if: `a="str1"; b="str1b"`

Comment: Works for me. The catch is when run from terminal, "equal" means "failure" (non-zero return code).

Comment: You're right. My apologies. When I ran it, I was inconsistently thinking of the shell's idea of true/false and C's, which are the opposite way around.

Answer (score 0):

## C++ - <s>66</s> <s>57</s> 53

```
int c(char*a,char*b){return *a-*b?0:*a?c(++a,++b):1;}
```

with the ungolfed version:

```
int mystrcmp( char* a, char* b )
{
  // If the characters don't match, we're done
  if( *a - *b )
  {
      return 0;
  }
  
  // If they do match, and both were nulls, we are done 
  if( !*a )
  {
      return 1;
  }
  
  return mystrcmp( ++a, ++b );
}
```

Driver program in original post below.

---

*Old version:*
The golfed version:

```
int c(char*a, char*b){while(*a|*b)if(*a++-*b++)return 0;return 1;}
```

Here is a full driver program with comments:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int mystrcmp( char* a, char* b ) {
   // The comparison will continue as long as both *a and *b are not '\0'.
   // If one of them goes '\0' but the other does not, the strings are not 
   // of equal length and at that point we will return 0.
   while( *a | *b ) {
     // Compare the current character and return 0 if they are not equal.
     // *a++ will return the value of *a and then increment the pointer -
     // see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255147/does-p-increment-after-dereferencing
     if(*a++ - *b++) {
       return 0;
     }
   }

   // If we got here, both strings are equal up to and including the last '\0'.
   return 1;
}

int main()
{   
   // Prints 1
   cout << mystrcmp("Hello.", "Hello.") << endl;

   // Prints 1       
   cout << mystrcmp("Hello, world!", "Hello, world!") << endl;
   
   // Prints 0
   cout << mystrcmp("Hello", "Hello.") << endl;

   // Prints 0       
   cout << mystrcmp("Hello.", "Zello.") << endl;
   
   // Prints 0
   cout << mystrcmp("Hello", "Hallo") << endl;
   
   // Prints 0
   cout << "Hello World" << endl; 
   
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can drop the parentheses: `*a-*b?0:*a?c(++a,++b):1`

Comment: Thanks @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳, for some reason I thought there would a problem with the precedence.

Answer (score 0):

### C++ 30

```
#include<string>
std::string a = "test", b = a;
int main(){return!(a<b||a>b);}
```

---

I'm not counting the first two lines because:

> The strings should not be counted in the golf.

And [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43e99c361c55603b) are some tests.

Answer (score 0):

## Delphi (<strike>412</strike> <strike>83</strike> 75)

Can probably be done shorter but was fun to do, going to see if i can get some off.
**412 -> 83** Cant believe I missed this... Checks if s1 is in s2 and if s2 is in s1.
Saved 329 chars *Cheers*
**83 -> 75** Thanks to Manatwork. Changed check if s1 is in s2 and other way around. Saved 8 characters

```
const s1='string12';s2='string12';begin Write(Pos(s1,s2)*Pos(s2,s1)>0);end.
```

#### Ungolfed

```
const
  s1='string12';
  s2='string22';
begin
  Write(Pos(s1,s2)*Pos(s2,s1)>0);
end.
```

Comment: A few tests I made shows that `Pos(s1,s2)*Pos(s2,s1)>0` would also do it.

Answer (score 0):

### Dart - 15

Strings are stored in `a` en `b`.

```
[a].contains(b)
```

`[a]` creates a `List` with `a`.

Answer (score 0):

### Q - [3 bytes]

```
a:"string"
b:"string"

a~b
```

I think this is a valid answer as ~ isn't an equals operator.
From a Q tutorial:

> ~  asks whether two entities have the same contents.
>
> http://kx.com/q/d/primer.htm

Answer (score 0):

## C#

I know there's already a C# answer, I just wanted to show other options. :)

### boolean:

- 51

  ```
  !Convert.ToBoolean(new[]{a,b}.Distinct().Count()-1)
  ```

### 1 or 0:

- 32

  ```
  -new[]{a,b}.Distinct().Count()+2
  ```

Answer (score 0):

**C#**

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(StringEqual("pie","pie")); // true
}

bool Equals(int a,int b)
{
    var aBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(a);
    var bBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(b);

    return aBytes.SequenceEqual(bBytes);
}

bool StringEqual(string a,string b)
{
    int i = 0;
    return a.All((c) => Equals((int)c,(int)b[i++]));
}
```

Comment: why not just `a.SequenceEqual(b)` ???

Comment: @Habib I'm stupid. :D

Answer (score 0):

**C#**

I already posted the answer But just found a number of ways in C#

```
 var b = "abcdef";
 var a = "abcdef";
 // the best one is this.
 bool repace = a.Replace(b, "").Length < 1 && b.Replace(a, "").Length < 1;
 bool contsins = ("a" + a).Contains(b) && ("b" + b).Contains(a);
```

Comment: forget to mention considering string are not empty.

Answer (score 0):

### Javascrpt: 38 chars (without a-b declarations) || 31 without alert()

```
a="string";
b="string";

o={};o[a]=0;alert(o.hasOwnProperty(b))
```

sets an object key named the value of *a* -- checks for a key named the value of *b* in that object.

without alert:

```
o={};o[a]=0;o.hasOwnProperty(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

## J - 6 char

A J expression which tests for string equality without testing for string equality? Here's one:

```
e./a;b        NB. is a boxed in b boxed?
```

Not good enough? Want some more options? Go ahead, have some more, J has plenty.

```
<:#~.a;b      NB. (the number of the unique items among the two) - 1
1-{:~:a;b     NB. 1 - (whether the second item is unique, given the first)
2-#]/.~a;b    NB. 2 - (the number of piles the strings will sort themselves into)
+/(/:*\:)a;b  NB. is sorting them forwards the same as sorting them backwards?
A.|./:\:~a;b  NB. will sorting them forwards after sorting them backwards do anything?
```

The common subexpression here, `a;b`, is `a` linked to `b`. It puts `a` and `b` into boxes before appending them into a list. This is J's closest approximation to non-rectangular arrays: if you just tried to put the two strings in a 2-item list, the shorter would be padded with spaces on the right, which could result in you comparing `'a'` and `'a '` as equal.

Answer (score 0):

C#, pretty straightforward.

```
static bool equal(string s1, string s2)
{
    int i = 0;
    try { while (true) if (!isZero((int)s1[i] - (int)s2[i++])) return false; }
    catch { }
    return isEnd(s1, i) && isEnd(s2, i);
}

static bool isEnd(string s, int i)
{
    try { char c = s[i]; return false; }
    catch { }
    return true;
}

static bool isZero(int x)
{
    try { int y = 1 / x; return false; }
    catch { }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash, 14

Assuming strings are in A and B, then

```
[ -z ${A/$B} ]
```

will return a true (0) or false (1) value in $?.

How do I use it?

```
A="string";B="string";[ -z ${A/$B} ]&&echo same
```

How does it work?

${A/$B} replaces $B in $A with nothing. Only if $A=$B then result will be an empty string. [ -z<strike>n</strike> X ] tests for empty or null string and sets $? to 0 if empty.

Update: should be -z not -n in test.

Answer (score 0):

### C, 48 chars

```
c(char*a,char*b){return*a++-*b?0:!*b++||c(a,b);}
```

Recursion is often shorter than a loop.
Subtraction easily replaces a comparison.

Answer (score 0):

**Lua, 147**

```
a="string" b="string" y=string.byte s=string.sub m=math.abs c=1 for i=1,math.max(#a,#b) do d=y(s(a,i)) e=y(s(b,i))if not((d and e)and(m(d) - m(e)))then c=0 break end end
```

Assumes *a* and *b* are the strings. *c* should be 1 (true)

Answer (score 0):

### Python 56

```
a = "string"
b = "string"

not any(ord(x)*len(a)-ord(y)*len(b) for x,y in zip(a,b))
```

A bit longer than the shortest Python examples, but probably about the best I can do without using in or set notation (the former should probably be excluded, the latter has already been employed as succinctly as possible).

Answer (score 0):

## Rebol, 22

```
all[find a b find b a]
```

This will return `none` if strings are different.

Example usage in Rebol console:

```
>> a: "string"
== "string"

>> b: "string"
== "string"

>> c: "stringstring"
== "stringstring"

>> all [find a b find b a]
== "string"

>> all [find a c find c a] 
== none
```

By default Rebol is case insensitive.  So use `find/case` to enforce stricter test:

```
>> b: "STRING"
== "STRING"

>> all [find a b find b a] 
== "STRING"

>> all [find/case a b find/case b a]
== none
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript

Where `x = z` and `x != y`:

```
if( x.match(RegExp(z)) ) // Evaluates to True
 

if( x.match(RegExp(y)) ) // Evaluates to False
```

Comment: What if `z === 'Abc.efg'` and `x === 'Abcdefg'`?

Answer (score 0):

### Windows Batch (47)

```
@echo.>%1
@if exist %2 (exit /b 0)
@exit /b 1
```

This should be run in an empty directory each time ;)

It types a blank line into a file named with the first argument, and then checks if the second argument exists. For hardcoded strings, either replace the %1 and %2 or add `@if "%1"=="" %0 string1 string2` to the top of the file.

Comment: Do you have a reference for your “errorlevel isn't 0 by default” comment?

Answer (score 0):

## Java

```
import java.util.HashSet;
public class Equals {
    public static boolean equals(String s1, String s2){
        HashSet<String> sSet = new HashSet<>();
        sSet.add(s1);
        return !sSet.add(s2);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(equals("Apple","Tpple"));
    }
}
```

Comment: This can still be golfed a bit. Also you should include the bytecount in the title of your answer :]

Answer (score 0):

## perl, 20 bytes

Today I'm serving up perl two ways, saving a byte or two off the other perl solutions seen here. First, with hash slices, for 20 bytes:

```
@x{$a,$b}=();$_=%x%2
```

and then a port of the clever python solution above (also 20 bytes)

```
$_={$a,0,$b,1}->{$a}
```

Answer (score 0):

## C - 59

```
e(char*l,char*r){for(;*l&*r&&!(*l++^*r++););return!*l&!*r;}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby (18)

This one is a script using the exit status instead of a function's return value: 0 is success, 1+ is failure.

```
exit$*.uniq.size-1
```

Usage:

```
$ ruby equality.rb a b
$ echo $?
1
$ ruby equality.rb a a
$ echo $?
0
```

Answer (score 0):

## R, 4

`"string1"%in%"string2"` equivalent to `is.element("string1", c("string2"))`

Answer (score 0):

### D - <del>34</del> 27 bytes

```
!any!"a.length"(split(a,b))
```

Example use:

```
import std.stdio,std.string,std.algorithm;

void main() {
    auto a = "abcd";
    auto b = "abcd";

    writeln(!any!"a.length"(split(a,b)));
}
```

Output:

```
true
```

Answer (score 0):

## ~-~! (No Comment) - 1

#### (might not be legal)

```
|string|-|string|
```

`%` if they're equal, anything else if they're not. There's an issue though; ~-~! only accepts `%` or `~` (0 or 1) for conditionals; if it's neither, it throws an error. So you'd have to use `==~` to actually be able to use it properly. I don't think there /is/ a way to do this in ~-~! without the equality operator if this isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 124 Bytes

Subroutine that takes variant input `a` and `b` of the assumed type `variant\string` and outputs as a boolean variable to the VBE immediates window

```
Sub m(a,b)
c=1
For i=1To Len(a)
If Asc(Right(Left(a,i),1))-Asc(Right(Left(b,i),1)) Or Len(a)-Len(b) Then:c=0:Exit For
Next
Debug.?CBool(c)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Operation Flashpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Flashpoint:_Cold_War_Crisis) scripting language, 7 bytes

```
a in[b]
```

Strings are stored in variables `a` and `b` (as allowed by the question).

Interestingly, even if direct comparison would be allowed, this would be the only valid solution, because `a==b` performs a case-insensitive comparison, whereas the built-in `in` uses case-sensitive comparison for strings internally.

Answer (score 0):

## [shell], 22 bytes (almost any shell (sh,bash,ksh,zsh, etc), certainly POSIX ones)

```sh
a=string
b=string

c=${a#"$b"}
echo ${#c}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0kszvifaFtcUpSZl86VBGX8T7ZVqU5UVlJJUqrlSk3OyFdQUqlWTq5V@v8fAA)

Will output 0 if strings are equal, 1 if different. The less robust solution that doesn't deal with (`*`, `?` and `[` in `$b`) is two bytes shorter:

```sh
c=${a#$b}
echo ${#c}
```

Answer (score 0):

## PYTHON, 25

```
not bool(a.replace(b,''))
```

Explanation

An empty string is false in Python, so if we replace b with '' and check if it is empty that gives use true/false.

Comment: Welcome to the site! As a tip `not` will automatically cast to bool in python so there is no need for the `bool`.  However this answer doesn't work.  If a is the string `xx` and b is the string `x` then the replacement will be empty but the two are not equal.

Comment: If *both* `a.replace(b,'')` and `b.replace(a,'')` are empty then it will be equal so you can do something like `not a.replace(b,"")+b.replace(a,"")`.

Answer (score -1):

### C#

```
var b="string";
var a="string";
return  Regex.IsMatch(b, "^.{" + a.Length + "}$") && Regex.IsMatch(b,"^" + a + "$");
```

Comment: I am afraid this counts as one of the forbidden functions.

Comment: awh.. I hope now it is fine 
return Regex.IsMatch("^" + a + "$", b);
is it ?

Comment: According to your function, `a = "string.!?"` equals `b = "stringz".

Comment: again...... : P

Answer (score -1):

## Java - 54

First Golf:
Since all string's HashCode is the same with the same content, it can be useful.

```
(int)Math.abs(Math.signum(s.hashCode()-b.hashCode()));
```

Comment: This is wrong. Non-identical strings may have different hash codes.