# compare string without conditional operator

Tags: popularity-contest

Compare if three string variables with the same content, return `true` if they are or `false` if they are not without using conditional operators and bitwise operators.

e.g. in C# without `&& || ?:`

```
return  (string1==string2)==(string1==string3)==true;
```

PS: initial idea came from these [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22484127/352101)

Comment: Popularity contests shouldn't get the [tag:code-challenge] tag. I've removed that tag.

Comment: How about just... `if(string1==string2)return string2==string3;return false`

Comment: Many thanks @ProgramFOX, I'm new to PCG

Comment: Also, I think it's a good idea to ban bitwise operators. `true & true` is actually the same as `true && true`.

Comment: @mniip, I think your code is valid, just less interesting :)  Anyway, I'm not 100% sure if this question can raise any interesting answers at all. But I'm keen to find out and hence the question..

Comment: Trivial variant on [Determine if Strings are equal](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/23860/determine-if-strings-are-equal)

Comment: @PeterTaylor: It's not a duplicate, because that question doesn't allow the `==` operator and similar, but this question doesn't allow operators like conditional operators and bitwise operators such as `&&`.

Comment: @ProgramFOX, `&&` isn't a bitwise operator; few of the 63 answers to that question *can't* be trivially adapted to this one.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: I know `&&` is not a bitwise operator. I actually meant to give `&&` as an example to "conditional operators". Unfortunately, I can't edit it anymore.

Comment: @ProgramFOX, it's a Boolean operator. The only operator which I can find anyone describing as a conditional operator is `?:`.

Answer (score 2):

## GolfScript

```
1$=:a;=a+2="true""false"if
```

This program assumes three strings on the stack.

[Test online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyAiYWJjIiAiYWJjIiAiYWJjIgoKMSQ9OmE7PWErMj0idHJ1ZSIiZmFsc2UiaWY%3D)

How it works:

1. `1$` copies the second element on the stack (the second string) to the top of the stack.
2. `=:a;` returns `1` if the two top elements (the second and the third string) are equal; otherwise, `0`. Then, it stores this result in the variable `a` and it pops it from the stack. Now only the first and the second string remain on the stack.
3. `=` checks whether the first and the second string are equal.
4. `a+` puts the value of `a` on the stack and calculates the sum of `a` and the result of the previous comparison.
5. `2="true""false"if` puts `"true"` on the stack if the sum of the comparison results is equal to `2`: in this case, both comparisons returned true. If the sum is `1` or `0` then it puts `"false"` on the stack. This value is now the only one on the stack, and at the and of a program, GolfScript always outputs the values on the stack.

[Edit]

Thanks to Peter Taylor for pointing out that variables are not necessary:

```
1$=@@=+2="true""false"if
```

Comment: You don't need a variable. `@@` will push the top item on the stack down two. (And since idiomatic GolfScript is golfed, I prefer my answer to the question which I claim this one duplicates. Just change `(` to a suitable comparison).

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Thank you, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl

The function `CompareStrings` takes *any* number of strings and returns the strings `true` or `false`:

- `true` is returned if there are one or more strings and all strings are equal.
- `false` is returned if there is no string or at least two different strings.

```perl
sub CompareStrings (@) {
    my %hash = map { $_ => 1 } @_;
    return ('false', 'true')[not scalar(keys %hash) - 1];
}
```

The strings are put as keys in a hash. If there is at least one string and all strings are equal, then the hash has one key exactly. Otherwise there are zero or two or more keys. After 1 is subtracted the operator `not` maps the cases to the empty string and `1` that are used to select the result string (the empty string becomes 0).

```perl
sub CompareStrings (@) {
    my %hash = map { $_ => 1 } @_;
    return ('false', 'true')[not scalar(keys %hash) - 1];
}
```

**Complete script with test cases:**

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
$^W=1;

sub CompareStrings (@) {
    # several variants to initialize the hash, whose keys are the strings:
    # my %hash; @hash{@_} = (1) x @_;
    # my %hash; $hash{$_} = 1 for @_;
    my %hash = map { $_ => 1 } @_;
    return ('false', 'true')[not scalar(keys %hash) - 1];
}

# Testing

$\ = "\n";
print CompareStrings qw[];                  # false
print CompareStrings qw[foobar];            # true
print CompareStrings qw[hello hello];       # true
print CompareStrings qw[Hello World];       # false
print CompareStrings qw[abc abc abc];       # true 
print CompareStrings qw[abc abc def];       # false
print CompareStrings qw[abc def ghi];       # false
print CompareStrings qw[a a a a a a a a];   # true
print CompareStrings qw]a a a a oops a a];  # false

__END__
```