# Determine if a number is less than another

Tags: code-golf, number

## Introduction

Your job is to write a function or program that detects if a number `a` is less than a number `b`.

**But...** You are not allowed to use built-in alternatives for equals, less than, greater than, less than or equal to, greater than or equal to, or not equal to operators. (Writing your own implementation is allowed.) Similar alternative methods/alternatives in other languages that are designed to replace those operations are also restricted.

You **are** allowed to use operators that are not banned, e.g. bitwise operators and the not operator (but it would be better if your answer did not have the not operator).

## Challenge

Simply return a truthy or falsy value (or something that evaluates in the language to true or false like 0 or 1) to indicate whether `a` is less than `b`. The winner of the challenge can be determined by the shortest code. External sources are not allowed, but anonymous functions are. Explaining your answer is not mandatory, but encouraged.

## Example using Javascript:

```js
(a,b)=>!!Math.max(0,b-a) //remove the !! for truthy and falsy numbers
/*Explanation
(a,b)                    Parameters a and b
     =>                  Function is
       !!                returns true if truthy and false if falsy
         Math.max(0,b-a) returns the greater number, 0 or b-a
*/
```

## Examples of Input and Output

```
Input | Output
------|-------
1, 3  | true
2, 2  | false
3, 2  | false
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  The challenge you have linked is very old and not really a good example of a challenge. [I have currently voted to close that challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/23860/determine-if-strings-are-equal#comment469779_23860) and I am voting to close your challenge for the same reason. In the future you can visit our sandbox (linked in the sidebar) to get feedback ahead of time.

Comment: The core of the issue is that what consitutes a certain operation (e.g. `==` or `<`) is not very clear and varies wildly from language to language.

Comment: [Related meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8079/58563) in _Things to avoid when writing challenges_.

Comment: @a'_' That returns true for 3, 2 even though 3 is not less than 2...

Comment: @a'_' well you could use logical negation (decided that was too much) and bitwise operators.

Comment: @a'_' Some languages don't have a negate operator and some can do it in less than 5 bytes (see answer below) and I can't think of a javascript solution without the not operator that returns true or false.

Comment: I would try to avoid the “operator” word to make clear that bultin methods and functions would also be too boring. (For example: [`(1).__lt__(3)`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ8NQUy8@PqckPl7DWFPz/38A), [`1.<(3)`](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0DBUM9Gw1jz/38A), [`@cmpn{1;3;true;false;false}`](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/P8bR1iE5tyCv2tDa2LqkqDTVOi0xpxhK1v7/DwA).)

Comment: @a'_' that is `true`...

Comment: @a'_' I didn't add the restriction back but it's not encouraged now.

Comment: @WheatWizard What should I change and how should I change it; or should I just delete this question?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to improve the question.  However in my opinion it is not salvageable. The very core idea of do X but these X Y Z are banned is very very hard to make clear and concrete.  And even if you did, "do X without Y" is a challenge type that we have already kind of done to death.  I would recommend putting your effort coming up with a fresh idea rather than trying to patch this one up.

Comment: When you have a new idea the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=active) is the best place to start, since you can get feedback risk free before you post.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 2 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Requires `⎕IO←0`

```apl
⊃⍒
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/x91NT/qnfQ/Dch51NsHEe9qPrTe@FHbRCAvOMgZSIZ4eAb/T1MwVDDmSlMwUjACksYKRgA)

`⍒` gives the "grade". The indices into the argument that would stably sort it in descending order

- If the first element is less than the second, it gives `[1,0]`
- If the the elements are equal, it gives `[0,1]`
- If the second element is less than the second, it gives `[0,1]`

`⊃` picks the first element of that

- If the first element is less than the second, it gives `1`
- If the the elements are equal, it gives `0`
- If the second element is less than the second, it gives `0`

Comment: Hm, I guess this answer isn't useful.