# Output the nth digits of an integer

Tags: code-golf, math

**Without using strings** (except when necessary, such as with input or output) calculate the nth digit, **from the left**, of an **integer** (in base 10).

Input will be given in this format:

```
726433 5
```

Output should be:

```
3
```

as that is the fifth digit of "726433".

Input will **not** contain leading zeros, e.g. "00223".

Test cases / further examples:

```
9 1  ->  9
0 1  ->  0
444494 5  ->  9
800 2  ->  0
```

This is code golf; least amount of characters wins, but any built in functions such as "nthDigit(x,n)" are **not acceptable**.

Here's some pseudo-code to get you started:

```
x = number
n = index of the digit
digits = floor[log10[x]] + 1
dropRight = floor[x / 10^(digits - n)]
dropLeft = (dropRight / 10 - floor[dropRight / 10]) * 10
nthDigit = dropLeft
```

As you can see I'm new to code golf, and though I think it's a bit unfair that I ask a question before I've even answered one, I would really like to see what kind of responses this generates. :)

**Edit**: I was hoping for mathematical answers, so I cannot really accept answers that rely on converting strings to arrays or being able to access numbers as a list of digits.

## We have a winner

Written in "dc", **12** bytes. By *DigitalTrauma*.

Comment: Can this be just a function or must it need to handle I/O? If it does not need to handle I/O can it simply be a lambda instead of a function?

Comment: Your edit leaves it unclear as to what exactly you don't like. In particular, with "being able to access numbers as a list of digits", is it the use of arrays in any form that you don't like, or just the existence of built-in base conversion routines?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Arrays of digits are not OK, as one can easily just grab the nth item in the array. I am not sure how base-conversion works exactly, but it seems to easy.

Comment: Why is it a problem to build a list of digits? That is highly mathematical - it represents the number as a polynomial.

Comment: @2rs2ts If you can create a list of digits mathematically, i.e. without parsing a string into an array, then it could be acceptable.

Comment: This is an easy problem, so of course the solutions are easy. Your approach using logarithms and division isn't difficult; it's just longer in some languages to do the logarithm and division than to build up a array of `x/10^i` and then select the appropriate element of the array. Edit: ah, so your problem isn't with the use of arrays? In that case you won't have any complaints about my 16-char solution.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I see. I will accept arrays if they aren't created by directly parsing the input into an array. :)

Comment: What if the input is, f.e., `9 2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [dc](http://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/), 12 bytes

```
?dZ?-Ar^/A%p
```

This is a mathematical answer.  Here's how it works:

- `?` read input number and push to stack
- `d` duplicate top of stack
- `Z` Pops value off the stack, calculates and pushes the number of digits
- `?` read digit index and push to stack
- `-` subtract digit index from digit count
- `A` push 10 to the stack
- `r` swap top 2 values on stack
- `^` exponentiate 10 ^ (digit count - digit index)
- `/` divide number by result of exponentiation
- `A` push 10 to the stack
- `%` calculate the number mod 10 to get the last digit and push to top of stack
- `p` pop and print the top of stack

In action:

```
$ { echo 987654321; echo 1; } | dc ndigit.dc
9
$ { echo 987654321; echo 2; } | dc ndigit.dc
8
$ { echo 987654321; echo 8; } | dc ndigit.dc
2
$ { echo 987654321; echo 9; } | dc ndigit.dc
1
$
```

Comment: I think you're the winner. This is the third shortest code, but the shortest 2 used `base conversion -> arrays`.

Answer (score 5):

### GolfScript (10 bytes)

```
~(\10base=
```

This assumes input is as a string (e.g. via stdin). If it's as two integers on the stack, the initial `~` should be removed, saving 1 char.

If the base conversion is considered to fall foul of the built-in functions rule, I have a 16-char alternative:

```
~~)\{}{10/}/=10%
```

Comment: Your first program with the base conversion outputs the first digit only if you enter "0" and the second if you enter "1". http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=MjcwNiAxCgpcMTBiYXNlPQ%3D%3D

Comment: @kukac67, fixed.

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell 60 bytes and readable

```
nth x n
        | x < (10^n) = mod x 10
        | True = nth (div x 10) n
```

no strings involved!

```
*Main> nth 1234567 4
4
```

Comment: This can be [golfed down to 36](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v0I5r6bCRsPQIC5P0zY3P0WhQsHQoMbQxsg2JbMMzFHO@5@bmJmnYKuQks@loFBQlJlXoqCiYGhkbGJqZq5s8h8A)

Comment: Wow you fought for every byte.  1<2" instead of "true" - cute.

Comment: It's [what we do around here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/25430/3527)...

Answer (score 4):

## CJam - 7

```
l~(\Ab=
```

CJam is a new language I am developing, similar to GolfScript - http://sf.net/p/cjam. Here is the explanation:

`l` reads a line from the input
`~` evaluates the string (thus getting the two numbers)
`(` decrements the second number
`\` swaps the numbers
`A` is a variable preinitialized to 10
`b` does a base conversion, making an array with the base-10 digits of the first number
`=` gets the desired element of the array

The program is basically a translation of Peter Taylor's solution.

Comment: I would argue putting base 10 digits into an array is more of a string operation than a mathematical one.

Answer (score 3):

## J - <strike>15</strike> 24 char

A sufficiently "mathematical answer".

```
(10|[<.@*10^]-10>.@^.[)/
```

Same results as below, but is endowed with the mystical quality of being mathematical.

---

The short version, using base-10 expansion.

```
({0,10&#.inv)~/
```

We prepend a 0 to adjust for 1-based indexing.

Usage:

```
   ({0,10&#.inv)~/ 1234567 3
3
   ({0,10&#.inv)~/ 444494 5
9
```

Comment: Strings are not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

## bc (driven by bash), <strike>41</strike> 29

I think this is the first answer to do this mathematically and not with strings:

```
bc<<<"$1/A^(length($1)-$2)%A"
```

The use of `length()` perhaps seems a bit stringy, but the bc man page talks about number of digits and not length of string:

> ```
>   length ( expression )
>           The value of the length function is the  number  of  significant
>           digits in the expression.
> ```

Output:

```
$ ./ndigits.bc.sh 726433 5
3
$ ./ndigits.bc.sh 9 1
9
$ ./ndigits.bc.sh 0 1
0
$ ./ndigits.bc.sh 444494 5
9
$ ./ndigits.bc.sh 800 2
0
$
```

Comment: @kukac67 I appreciate the acceptance vote!  But I think it is customary for code-golf questions to be left open more than 2 hours to encourage more answers.  Perhaps a week or so.  I won't be offended if you de-accept this answer :)

Comment: ok. I will de-accept then. Hope you don't win! :P

Answer (score 2):

## Python 127

```
def f(i,n):
 b=10;j=i/b;k=1;d=i-j*b
 while j>0:
  k+=1;j/=b
 if n>k:
  return -1
 while k>n:
  k-=1;j/=b;i/=b;d=i-j*b
 return d
```

Comment: You don't need to define it as a fn: `def f(i,n): ... return d`

Comment: You don't need to sanity-check the `if n>k: return -1` case.

Comment: ...and you certainly don't need to make a first-pass just to count k (the number of digits in i), in order to sanity-compare it to n.

Answer (score 2):

## C, 50

This uses arrays.

```c
main(int c,char**a){putchar(a[1][atoi(a[2])-1]);}
```

Just ignore all the warnings.

And yes, in C, strings are really just arrays, so this is sort of cheap.

---

More Mathematical:

## C, 83

```c
main(int c,char**a){printf("%d",(atoi(a[1])/pow(10,strlen(a[1])-atoi(a[2])))%10);}
```

Comment: isn't it using string/array functions?

Comment: First one does, like it says ;) The second one obviously doesn't, apart from the strlen, which I chose simply because it's shorter than using log. If that's a problem it's an easy fix, I can add it when I get home.

Comment: There we go, added the purely mathematical version.

Comment: Math - not even once!

Answer (score 1):

### Tcl (42 bytes, lambda):

```tcl
{{x y} {expr $x/10**int(log10($x)+1-$y)%10}}
```

### (49 bytes, function):

```tcl
proc f {x y} {expr $x/10**int(log10($x)+1-$y)%10}
```

### (83 bytes, if we need to accept input from shell):

```tcl
puts [expr [lindex $argv 0]/10**int(log10([lindex $argv 0])+1-[lindex $argv 1])%10]
```

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: Added explanation. It's just the most obvious way to do it mathematically. How you'd do it on paper.

Comment: I think you're counting from the wrong end.

Comment: Hmm.. yeah. Looks like it. I'll revise it to count form the left.

Comment: I'll accept the 31 bytes. Though how can the lambda be run? Does Tcl have an interpreter which can use it? Or only as part of a program which defines the arguments?

Comment: Sorry, it's 42 bytes unless you accept counting from the right. To run the lambda in tcl you just call it using the apply command: `apply $lambda $number $index`

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica - <s>24</s> 23

This one is kind of obvious :)

```
IntegerDigits[#][[#2]]&
```

Example:

```
IntegerDigits[#][[#2]]& [726433, 5]
```

Output:

```
3
```

You can get it shorter by hard-coding two integers, e.g.

```
IntegerDigits[n][[m]]
```

but then you first have to write `n = 726433; m = 5;`. The function call felt more similar to a program.

Comment: You can drop the number `1`.

Comment: Now this is cheating.. :D

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 142

I'm not sure I understood the question correctly, but this is what I think you wanted: read stdin (string), make the two numbers int (not string), do some algorithmic things, and then output the result (string). I crammed it into 142 chars, which is way too much:

```hs
import System.Environment
a%b|a>9=div a 10%(b+1)|1<2=b
x#n=x`div`10^(x%1-n)`mod`10
u[a,b]=read a#read b
main=fmap(u.words)getContents>>=print
```

example usage:

```hs
> echo 96594 4 | getIndex
9
```

Answer (score 1):

### Scala (<s>133</s> 99 bytes):

Works for all positive inputs. Divides by 10 to the power of the digit looked for from the right, then takes it modulo 10.

```
def k(i:Array[String])={val m=i(0).toInt
(m*Math.pow(10,i(1).toInt-1-Math.log10(m)toInt)).toInt%10}
```

Thank you for noticing the bug in the previous formula. This one is shorter.

Comment: I like it! :) Up-voted

Comment: Tested the solution: k(Array("1234", "7")) which gives 9. Does it not work for n > #digits(x) ?

Comment: It's because 10^-1 is not exact in this notation, so there is a rounding error when you take 10%pow(10,-1) which should have given zero but gave 0.0999 instead. Corrected my answer to accomodate this side-effect.

Answer (score 1):

**C 145**

Program finds distance from end of integer and divides until index is reached then uses modulus 10 to get the last digit.

```
int main()
{
int i,a,b,d,n;
scanf("%d %d",&i,&a);
d=(int)(log(i)/log(10))+1;
n=d-a;
while(n--){i=(int)(i/10);}
b=i%10;
printf("%d",b);
}
```

Comment: This can be golfed significantly.  [Start with these tips](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2203/tips-for-golfing-in-c)

Comment: For a start, the (int) casts and associated parens are unnecessary

Comment: I couldn't resist.  I golfed it down to 87 chars: `i,a;main(){scanf("%d%d",&i,&a);for(a=log(i)/log(10)+1-a;a--;)i/=10;printf("%d",i%10);}`.

Answer (score 1):

## Wolfram Alpha - between 40 and 43

Of course, I can totally defend that using `IntegerDigits` is a trick that does not fall under

> any built in functions such as "nthDigit(x,n)"

But because my previous answer still felt like cheating a little bit, here's an alternative. Unfortunately it's quite a bit longer, but I didn't see how to shorten it any more than I did.

Counting in a similar way as before (with the ampersand, without passing in any arguments),

```
Mod[Trunc[#/10^(Trunc[Log10[#]]-#2+1)],10]&
```

has 43 characters. By negating the exponent and shuffling the terms around, I can lose one arithmetic operator (`10^(...)x` will be interpreted as multiplication)

```
Mod[Trunc[10^(#2-Trunc[Log10[#]]-1)#],10]&
```

<s>I don't have Mathematica at hand to test, I doubt that it will be</s>As I suspected (and as was kindly [verified by kukac67](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/25534/output-the-nth-digits-of-an-integer/25587?noredirect=1#comment55296_25587)) in Mathematica this is not accepted, but it [runs in WolframAlpha](http://wolfr.am/1sAO8mu).

I am in doubt about the use of `RealDigits`, because I restricted myself from using `IntegerDigits` for this answer and they are quite similar. However, if I allow myself to include it (after all, it doesn't return the integers directly, just how *many* of them there are), I can slash off another two characters:

```
Mod[Trunc[10^(#2-RealDigits[#]-1)#],10]&
```

Comment: I tried it in Mathematica, it doesn't output a value. The 43 character one ouputs this:
`Mod[Trunc[57 2^(3 - Trunc[Log[456]/Log[10]])5^Trunc[Log[456]/Log[10]]], 10]`

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much. Wolfram Alpha is a bit more lenient in interpreting input. Luckily I gave it the correct header ;)

Comment: But I see it does work on WolframAlpha.

Comment: {edit} Although I see the link is broken... apparently doesn't like `[` characters even when they are encoded. I'll pull it through an URL shortener. {edit2} Apparently W.Alpha has one - changed the link.

Answer (score 1):

## R (60)

Solved the problem using log10 to calculate the number of digits. The special case x==0 costs 13 character, sigh.

```
f=function(x,n)if(x)x%/%10^(trunc(log10(x))-n+1)%%10 else 0
```

Ungolfed:

```
f=function(x,n)
  if(x) 
    x %/% 10^(trunc(log10(x)) - n + 1) %% 10
  else
    0
```

Usage

```
> f(898,2)
[1] 9
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript - 84

```
p=prompt,x=+p(),m=Math;r=~~(x/m.pow(10,~~(m.log(x)/m.LN10)+1-+p()));p(r-~~(r/10)*10)
```

Purely mathematical, no strings, none of them. Takes the first number in the first prompt and the second number in the second prompt.

**Test Case**:

```
Input: 97654 5
Output: 4

Input: 224658 3
Output: 4
```

**Ungolfed Code:**

```
p = prompt,
x = +p(), // or parseInt(prompt())
m = Math;

r = m.floor( x / m.pow(10, m.floor(m.log(x) / m.LN10) + 1 - +p()) )
//                                               ^-- log(10) ^-- this is `n`

p(r - ~~(r / 10) * 10) // show output
```

Answer (score 1):

### perl,  <s>38, 36</s>    no *30* characters

(not counting the linefeed)

This is arguably cheating due to the command switch, but thanks for letting me play :-)

```
~/$ cat ndigits.pl
say((split//,$ARGV[0])[$ARGV[1]-1]);
~/$ tr -cd "[:print:]" < ndigits.pl |wc -m 
36
~/$ perl -M5.010 ndigits.pl 726433 5 
3
```

**edit**:

Was able to remove 2 characters:

```
 say for(split//,$ARGV[0])[$ARGV[1]-1];
 say((split//,$ARGV[0])[$ARGV[1]-1]);
```

... then 6 more:

```
 say((split//,shift)[pop()-1]);
```

**How**

We split the input of the first argument to the script `$ARGV[0]` by character (`split//`) creating an zero indexed array; adding one to the second argument `$ARGV[1]` to the script then corresponds to the element at that position in the string or first argument.  We then hold the expression inside `()` as a one element list which `say` will iterate through. For the shorter short version we just `shift` in the first argument and use the remaining part of @ARGV to use for the index - once `shift`ed only the second argument remains so we `pop()` it and subtract 1.

Is this supposed to be a math exercise? I just realized I'm indexing a string read from input, so ... I guess I lose??  Mark me up if I make sense in parallel golf course and I will try again - more mathematically - in a separate answer.

cheers,

Comment: Yup, sorry, **Without using strings**.  Welcome to PPCG anyway!

Comment: OK sorry 'bout that ... so far my mathematical approaches are not very golf-worthy :-)

Answer (score 0):

## C, 94

```
main(x,y,z,n){scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);for(z=x,n=1-y;z/=10;n++);for(;n--;x/=10);printf("%d",x%10);}
```

## C, 91, invalid because  of using arrays.

```
main(x,y,z){int w[99];scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);for(z=0;x;x/=10)w[z++]=x%10;printf("%d",w[z-y]);}
```

Comment: I disallowed arrays in a edit (before you posted this)... But I like how you did this. :)

Comment: OK, I  wasn't looking properly. I've added a solution avoiding arrays.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 58

Using math only

`<?$n=$argv[1];while($n>pow(10,$argv[2]))$n/=10;echo $n%10;`

Comment: Doesn't this find from the right?

Comment: You can save 1 char by changing it to `echo$n%10`.

Comment: @Trimsty no, it actually loops until entered number is no longer bigger than 10^x, x being the digit number. So, for example, if you enter 3457 as a number and 2 as a digit, it will take away the last digit until the number becomes smaller than 100 (10^2). That means it will take away 5 and 7, because then 34 remains and it is not bigger than 100. Then it just outputs the last digit (4).

Comment: But it is true that if the second number is bigger than the number of digits, you output 9 and not zero

Comment: I see, it outputs last digit if the number if bigger than the number of digits. If you enter 1234 and 5th digit, you will get 4 since 1234 i already less than 10^5.

Answer (score 0):

## ~-~! - <s>94</s> 93

Bends the rules a bit - it's a function that takes n as input and assumes the number to find digit n of is stored in `'''''` - and ~-~! doesn't support floats.

```
'=~~~~~,~~:''=|*==~[']<''&*-~>,'|:'''=|*==%[%]~+*/~~~~/~~|:''''=|'''''/''&<<'''&'''''>-*-~>|:
```

`'''''=~~~~,~~,~~,~~,~~,~~:''''''=''''&~:` will result in `''''''` being `~~` (2) (''''' = 128).

Comment: Hm... Yet another esoteric language?

Comment: @VisioN it isn't really esoteric, just that the only native data type is a number and it can't interact with the os/internet. http://esolangs.org/wiki/No_Comment

Comment: Well, to me every syntax that can't be easily read by a human being is esoteric. And yes, Perl is also esoteric according to this theory `:)`

Comment: @VisioN It gets easy to read after a while. :P

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2.7 (89 bytes)

I transform the integer into a "polynomial" by using a list of digits. I know you say you can't accept that, but I don't see why not since it uses the mathematical concept of numbers being represented as polynomials of their bases. It will only fail when the integer passed in is `0`, but you said no padded zeroes ;)

```python
import sys;v=sys.argv;p,x,n=[],int(v[1]),int(v[2])
while x:p=[x%10]+p;x//=10
print p[n-1]
```

Run as `test.py`:

```python
$ python test.py 726489 5
8
```

I assume you wanted shell input and that I couldn't make use of the fact that the input would be strings. Skipping shell input it's just 43 bytes, with:

```python
p=[]
while x:p=[x%10]+p;x//=10
print p[n-1]
```

Although I use some unnecessary iteration, I save some bytes by not adding an additional decrement on `n`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Extended BrainFuck](http://sylwester.no/ebf/): 49

```
+[>>,32-]<<-[<<-],49-[->>>[>>]+[<<]<]>>>[>>]<33+.
```

Usage:

```
% bf ebf.bf < nth-digit.ebf > nth-digit.bf
% echo "112234567 7" | bf nth-digit.bf 
5
```

I'm not ectually using any special features of EBF except the multiplication operator (eg. `10+ => ++++++++++`). Other than that it's mostly pure [BrainFuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck)

How it works:

```
+                ; Make a 1 in the first cell
[>>,32-]         ; while cell is not zero: read byte 2 to the right and reduce by 32 (space)
<<-[<<-]         ; move back to the first cell by reducing every cell with 1
,49-             ; read index, reduce by 49 so that ascii 1 becomes 0
[->>>[>>]+[<<]<] ; use that to fill a trail of breadcrumbs to the desired number
>>>[>>]          ; follow the breadcrumbs
<33+.            ; go to value part, increase by 33 (32 + 1 which we substracted) and print
```

## Scheme (R6RS): 100 (without unnecessary whitespace)

```scm
(let*((x(read))(n(read))(e(expt 10(-(floor(+(/(log x)(log 10))1))n))))
  (exact(div(mod x(* e 10))e)))
```

Answer (score 0):

## awk - 53

```
{for(d=10^9;!int($1/d)||--$2;d/=10);$0=int($1/d)%10}1
```

1. trim digits by division, starting with max possible for 32 bit unsigned int
2. when we hit the left side of the integer, int($1 / d) returns non-zero
3. continue n ($2) digits past that

Ungolfed:

```
{
    for(d = 1000000000; int($1 / d) != 0 || --$2; d /= 10);
    print int($1 / d) % 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Scala (83)

Does not use any Scala special features. Rather the standard solution.

```
def f(x:Int,n:Int)=if(x==0)0 else x/(math.pow(10,math.log10(x).toInt-n+1)).toInt%10
```

Ungolfed:

```
def f(x:Int,n:Int) = 
  if(x==0)
    0
  else
    x / (math.pow(10, math.log10(x).toInt - n + 1)).toInt % 10
```

Answer (score 0):

## Julia 37

```
d(x,y)=div(x,10^int(log10(x)-y+1))%10
```

Owing to the builtin ^ operator.  Arbitrary precision arithmetic allows for any size int.

Sample

```
julia> d(1231198713987192871,10)
3
```

Answer (score 0):

### perl (slightly more mathy/not very golfy) - 99 chars

```
 ~/$ cat ndigits2.pl
  ($n,$i)=@ARGV;
  $r=floor($n/10**(floor(log($n)/log(10)+1)-$i));
  print int(.5+($r/10-floor($r/10))*10);
```

Run it as:

```
 perl -M5.010 -MPOSIX=floor ndigits.pl 726433 1
```

Answer (score 0):

### Perl6 - 85 chars

```perl
my ($n,$i)=@*ARGS;
my$r=$n/10**(log10($n).round-$i);
say (($r/10-floor($r/10))*10).Int;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Smalltalk, 44

Although dc is unbeatable, here is a Smalltalk solution:

arguments, n number; d digit-nr to extract:

```
[:n :d|(n//(10**((n log:10)ceiling-d)))\\10]
```