# Calculator that adds char values

Tags: code-golf

## Task

Build a calculator, that takes any string, from a file, stdin or whatever, and adds up all the values of the chars.

Example

```
Input
Hello World!

Output
1085
```

## Rules

The calculator needs to accept just ASCII encoding.

The shortest code wins.

## Notes

Regarding to the comment of m.buettner, I need to say, I didn't thought of the multibyte part.
So I leave it as a bonus thing aswell.
The calculator should be run as written, so no need to modify before compiling or interpreting.

## Bonus

Thanks to [Synthetica](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/18638/synthetica), here is one more bonus,

> The program that has the lowest output when you use its code as its input <strike>wins</strike> gets a star.

I don't want to modify it completly.

If you write it additional to output the (right) value in UTF-8 you get a star.

The code that executes fastest on my Laptop (Lenovo Yoga 13 Intel Core i5 3317U 1.7Ghz, 8GB RAM, 128GB SSD, Intel HD 4000, Windows 8) gets a star.

Web codes will run first under IE11 with [chakra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chakra_(JScript_engine)) and then in FireFox 29.0.1 with [SpiderMonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpiderMonkey_(software))

Linux code will run on a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian.

The teststring is this:

```
q/%8hnp>T%y?'wNb\},9krW &D9']K$n;l.3O+tE*$*._B^s!@k\&Cl:EO1zo8sVxEvBxCock_I+2o6 yeX*0Xq:tS^f)!!7=!tk9K<6#/E`ks(D'$z$\6Ac+MT&[s[]_Y(`<g%"w%cW'`c&q)D$0#C$QGf>?A$iawvc,}`9!('`c&q)D$0#C$QGf>?A$iawvc,}`9!(
```

Have fun coding :)

## Bonusscoring

I plan to do the scoring at this Saturday so the 07.06.14, all answers after that date won't get bonus points ;)

You can download the code I gonna use for testing [here](https://github.com/DerKnerd/Application-Speedtest) feel free to fork and improve it :)

Little update because of the bonus, my laptop is partially broken so I will do it probably next weekend, I am really sorry for that :(

Comment: [tag:code-golf] and [tag:fastest-code] are conflicting win criteria, you need to choose one of them.

Comment: @KyleKanos I changed it, I chose code-golf, cause fastest-code is just a bonus ;)

Comment: I get 1085 for `Hello World!` using two different languages for ASCII values on my computer.

Comment: @KyleKanos Damn, I forgot the bang at the end...

Comment: He probably forgot to add the '!'. edit you were 3 seconds faster...

Comment: @m.buettner I didn't thought of that, I edited the task a bit.

Comment: Could one please explain the downvotes?

Comment: My guess is that the downvotes indicate that it's not really a good problem.

Comment: @KyleKanos could you explain why you think that it could be not a good problem? It is my first code-golf, I would like to improve ^_^

Comment: @Knerd mainly, because it's a bit too trivial in most languages (as you can see from the length of the submissions you already got)

Comment: @m.buettner Good to know, so more heavy golfs than easy ones I guess. I'll keep that in mind :)

Comment: It's kind of a shame that you forgot the huge oppurtunity for a great special code golf: the program that has the lowest output when you use its code as its input wins

Comment: @Synthetica damn, you are good :D I think I gonna add this as a bonus :)

Comment: Full program, or just a function?  e.g. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/30232/11259 vs http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/30230/11259

Comment: @DigitalTrauma it should run like it is written so no adjustments needed

Comment: What is a "star"? Is it advantageous? Do that reduce my byte count, or make me win in the event of a tie?

Comment: Could the input contain a null byte?

Answer (score 10):

## GolfScript, 4 characters

```
{+}*
```

Simply uses the fold operator (`*`) to add up all the characters.

If it has to work with the empty string, 9 chars:

```
{{+}*}0if
```

Thanks to @PeterTaylor for providing an alternative 6-char version that works with empty string:

```
0\{+}/
```

Comment: Does not work on the empty string.

Comment: @Howard Good point; edited.

Comment: `0\{+}/` supports empty string

Comment: @Doorknob sorry for the stupid question, how to I input data? I use http://golfscript.apphb.com/

Comment: @Knerd You can download the interpreter and pipe input into it, or you could just use a string literal in the online version to mimic STDIN.

Comment: @Knerd E.g. like in [this example](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyJIZWxsbyBXb3JsZCEiCgowXHsrfS8%3D&run=true).

Comment: @Howard Thanks for the example, I was nearly stuck :/

Comment: `\{+}/` what sort of emoticon is this?

Comment: @immibid A cyclops with a weirdly shaped eye. :-P (or, in GolfScript, the "swap-and-add-each" face!)

Comment: @Doorknob don't forget that the cyclops is excited and or rejoicing! There is a reason he is waving his `\ /` arms around like that!

Answer (score 7):

## APL (8)

```
+/⎕UCS⍞
```

Explanation:

- `+/` sum of
- `⎕UCS` unicode values of
- `⍞` character input

Comment: What would be the result for `Hello World!`?

Comment: @Knerd: `1085`. It wouldn't be correct if it gave another output. It sums the values of the Unicode codepoints of the characters.

Comment: ok, I didn't got what the `⍞` means ;)

Comment: @knerd: `⍞` means read a line from the keyboard

Comment: Do you know an APL interpreter that is free?

Comment: @knerd [NARS2000](http://www.nars2000.org/)

Comment: OP allows input from "whatever", so you don't need the final ⍞. This would make it an unnamed atop (2-train), which could be named or parenthesized before applying to a character string.

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell 36

```
main=interact$show.sum.map fromEnum
```

Comment: From where does it read the text?

Comment: stdin. `$ printf "Hello World!" | ./charsum`

Comment: ok, I couldn't get it run on my Windows machine, I gonna try it on the rpi when I am at home

Comment: When I execute your code, I just get the string "Hello World!" as Output. This is my commandline: `ECHO "Hello World! | ghci charsum.hs`

Comment: You are missing a quote it seems.

Comment: Oh sorry, the quote is in, I forgot to type it -_- But that doesn't change the result.

Comment: `D:\tests>type hw.txt
    Hello World!
    D:\tests>type hw.txt | sum.exe
    1085`

Comment: use `interact` and `show` instead of `getContents>>=print`: `main=interact$show.sum.map fromEnum`

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of `interact`. The worst part is that it's right under `getContents`, which I purposefully looked up in hoogle...

Answer (score 6):

## Shell+GNU tools, 29 bytes

```
echo `od -An -tuC`|tr \  +|bc
```

Takes input from stdin:

```
$ printf "%s" 'Hello World!' | ./addchars.sh 
1085
$
```

Own score: 2385

---

## c, 52 bytes

```
c;main(p){while(~(p=getchar()))c+=p;printf("%d",c);}
```

Compile with (some warnings produced):

```
gcc addchars.c -o addchars
```

Takes input from stdin:

```
$ printf "%s" 'Hello World!' | ./addchars 
1085 $
```

Own score: 4354

Comment: This is great answer. CodeBlocks with GNU compiler always complains if variables have no type e.g int c, main(int p). So I think these should be included in your answer.

Comment: @bacchusbeale I added a note about compilation warnings, but I think this is generally par-for-the-course when golfing in c.  As long as the code compiles and runs as expected, then warnings can be ignored.  See http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2230/11259 and http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2204/11259.  Of course production code is a different matter entirely.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma are all those spaces actually necessary? Can the Shell not ignore the whitespace and use the - to mark new parameters?

Comment: @AshwinGupta Are you talking about the `od` command? `od -AntuC` does not do the same as `od -An -tuC`.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma yeah I was. I meant couldn't you do `od-An-tuC` or `od -An-tuC`

Comment: @AshwinGupta Have you tried it?  `od-An-tuC` is parsed as one token, and `-An-tuC` will be passed as one arg, which programs don't typically attempt to parse further due to all the potential ambiguities

Comment: @DigitalTrauma nah I can't try I have Windows not Linux shell.

Answer (score 6):

## Javascript (*ES6*)  51

```javascript
alert([...prompt(x=0)].map(y=>x+=y.charCodeAt())|x)
```

Comment: @nderscore Can you explain what the `...` before the `prompt` does? Is this a new ES6 thing or is it pre-ES6?

Comment: @WallyWest It's called a [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and it's part of the ES6 draft.

Comment: @nderscore So If I'm understanding the spread operator syntax, your use of `[...prompt(x=0)]` has taken the prompt with a default value of 0 (which goes later to be used in the sum), and applies that input as an array of characters...? Which technically would be the same as `prompt(x=0).split("")`, right?

Comment: @WallyWest `prompt(x=0)` means "set x to 0, call `prompt` with the value of setting x to 0", which is to say, 0. It would be equivalent to write `(x=0,prompt(x))`

Answer (score 6):

## 8086 Assembly (16-bit) - <strike>47</strike> 41 bytes

The contents of the `test.com` file are:

```
98 01 c3 b4 01 cd 21 3c 0d 75 f5 89 c7 c6 05 24
89 d8 b1 0a 4f 31 d2 f7 f1 80 ca 30 88 15 09 c0
75 f2 89 fa b4 09 cd 21 c3
```

Actual work is done in the first 11 bytes; I need the rest to print the result in decimal notation.

Source code (give as input to the DOS `debug.com` assembler):

```
a
; input the string; count the sum
    cbw
    add bx, ax
    mov ah, 1
    int 21
    cmp al, d
    jne 100
; Prepare for output: stuff an end-of-line marker
    mov di, ax
    mov [di], byte 24
    mov ax, bx
    mov cl, a
; 114
; Divide by 10; write digits to buffer
    dec di
    xor dx, dx
    div cx
    or  dl, 30
    mov [di], dl
    or  ax, ax
    jne 114
; Print the string
    mov dx, di
    mov ah, 9
    int 21
    ret

rcx 29
n test.com
w
q
```

Some notes on the code:

- Only handles one line (up to end-of-line character 13); hangs if no end-of-line
- Only 7-bit characters are supported (results are incorrect otherwise)
- Outputs 0 for empty input
- Cannot handle output greater than 64K
- Instruction at address 0x10d overwrites itself (pure coincidence)
- Have to use DOS emulators like [DosBox](http://www.dosbox.com/) to assemble and run this program

Comment: How can you understand that? o.O

Comment: Love the brutality of just writing the output right into your code :)  BTW, You can -2 bytes in the "Prepare for output" section by replacing `mov di, ax` with `xchg ax, di` and also `mov ax, bx` with `xchg ax, bx`. Nice work!

Comment: You could also use `si` instead of `di` for the output buffer pointer since on all mainstream versions of DOS [`si` is initialized to `100h` by default](http://www.fysnet.net/yourhelp.htm) saving one my byte by removing the `xchg ax, di`.

Comment: OR (last one I promise) you could use `bx` for your pointer and move `mov cl, 0ah` and `xchg ax, bx` above `mov byte ptr [bx], '$'` and it'll use the `0x10d` address as you had it before. Same 38 byte size as above though.

Answer (score 6):

## [gs2](https://github.com/nooodl/gs2/blob/master/gs2.py), 1 byte

```
d
```

`d` (`0x64` / `sum`), of course, sums up all bytes in standard input.

Answer (score 5):

### Ruby, <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
p~9+gets.sum
```

`sum` is a built-in function that sums the characters of a string. Subtracts 10 to account for the newline at the end of `gets`'s return value.

(Edited 4 years later to change `x-10` to `~9+x`... the value of `~9` is `-10`, but it lets us remove the space between `p` and its argument, saving a byte.)

Comment: I am not familiar with Ruby at all, could you explain your code please?

Comment: gets is a function that reads a string from standard in until a newline is read, it returns a String.  String#sum adds the values of each character, which returns a Fixnum.  Fixnum#- is just subtraction. `p` is a method for outputting the debug value of something on a line.

Answer (score 5):

## CJam, 3 bytes (sum 260)

```
q1b
```

You can [try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q1b&input=Hello%20World!).
Thanks jimmy23013 for helping chop off 2 characters :)

**Explanation:**

```
q     read the input into a string  
1b    convert from base 1, treating each character as its numeric value
```

Comment: `q1b` is shorter.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3 - 28 bytes

```
print(sum(map(ord,input())))
```

Example run:

```
$ ./sum_string.py <<< 'Hello World!'
1085
```

Gets input from stdin, `map`s the `ord` function to it to get the ASCII value of each character, `sum`s it and `print`s.

Comment: Ninja'd, I had the exact same idea. +1 for that.

Comment: @TheRare So did I, even though mine was longer, because I used Python 2.7. I'm getting rusty ;)

Comment: @Synthetica I always use Python 2.7, on which the answer would have been `print sum(map(ord,raw_input()))`

Comment: @TheRare Which was my exact answer ;)

Comment: Nitpicking here, but you can make it perform better by changing `map(ord,input())` to `input().encode()`. Bytes objects can still be summed, and it stays the same length.

Answer (score 4):

### Befunge98, 6 bytes, sum: 445

```
2j@.~+
```

Any interpreter should be fine. I use [CCBI](http://users.tkk.fi/~mniemenm/befunge/ccbi.html).

Use as follows:

```
printf 'Hello World!' | ccbi calc.fg
```

Works for multibyte chars and empty strings.

**Explanation**

- `2j` - jump over the next two instructions (`@` and `.` - see below)
- `~` - put the next char on the stack
- `+` - add the code value of the new char to the current sum. The instruction pointer wraps to the beginning and the cycle repeats
- when `~` encounters an EOF it inverses the direction of the pointer and the two "hidden" instructions are executed:
- `.` - print the sum
- `@` - exit

Answer (score 4):

## Python, 24 bytes

This is shorter than any Python solution so far: an unnamed anonymous function, which takes the string as an argument, and returns the sum.

```py
lambda x:sum(x.encode())
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@59mm5OYm5SSqFBhVVyaq1Ghl5qXnJ@SqqGp@b@gKDOvRCNNQ8kjNScnXyE8vygnRVEJKAEA)

First, `x.encode()` transforms it into a `bytes` object. Then, `sum` adds the char-code values. As this is a lambda function, the value is implicity returned.

Additionally, one could have `lambda x:sum(map(ord,x))` for the same byte count.

Answer (score 2):

## Julia - <del>11</del> 7 characters, resultant sum = <del>943</del> 536

Since the question allows the input to come from whatever source you want, I choose an existing variable. Assume that `A` contains the string we wish to evaluate.

```
sum(A)1
```

As it turns out, you can sum the string directly, and it will evaluate... however, due to the way that summing of chars is handled, if there is an odd number of characters in the string, it will output a character, rather than an integer of any sort. As such, we force it to cast to int by multiplying by 1.

Old version:

```
sum(A.data)
```

Will output in a hexadecimal notation (if the sum is less than 256, it'll be `0x??`, otherwise it'll be 8 byte as `0x????????`). If used in code where the result is used, it will operate just like any other number (it's just how Julia displays unsigned ints).

To see the value of the result in decimal, enclose the above in `int()`, as in `int(sum(A.data))`.

For anybody who doesn't know Julia, you assign to `A` exactly the same way you do other assignments to variables. So, `A="Hello World!"` or `A="sum(n.data)"`. In the case where you need to put in `"` or `'` characters, there are multiple options, the easiest of which (because it avoids need for knowledge of the nuances of Julia string literals) is `A=readline()`, followed by simply typing in the string into STDIN (won't handle newlines, though). The escape sequence for newline is, as usual, `\n`, but I don't believe you can use that with readline().

Comment: +1 for the god damn clever solution ^^ Could you post, how to assign the test value to the variable `n`? I don't know Julia at all ;)

Comment: @Knerd - I've edited it in. Hope that helps.

Comment: Great, thank you. I try to test it later :)

Comment: Minor change - switched variable from `n` to `A` to reduce the resultant sum from 988 to 943.

Comment: OK, much bigger change - I realised that you can sum the string directly, rather than extracting the characters with `.data`; but because they're characters, they produce a character result for an odd number of characters. Multiplication by 1 corrects that.

Answer (score 2):

## Go (59 characters)

```
func d(s string)(t int){for _,x:=range s{t+=int(x)};return}
```

Everything in Go is utf8 by default. Codetext in ` delimeters run through itself gives an output of: 5399.

Comment: I have to say I'm rather surprised there's no `math.Sum` for use with `map` or similar

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell - 27

```
[char[]]$args[0]|measure -s
```

**Example**

```
> SumChars.ps1 'Hello World!'

Count    : 12
Average  : 
Sum      : 1085
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property :
```

Comment: 26 if you use `[char[]]"$args"|measure -s` as long as there is only one $arg entry.

Answer (score 2):

## SML, <del>42</del> 36

Just adding another language.

```
fun$x=foldl op+0(map ord(explode x))
```

Converts String to char array, calculates ascii number of each value and calculates the sum of all ascii numbers.

Comment: You can drop some spaces and the leading `;`. 36 bytes: https://tio.run/##DcpBCoAgEAXQq0zRQomiC7ivdYuWEWgRfB2xKby9uXzwHo/BQziUcr6hy@ZkWBDHflL@iMTJKpcj2DrKWpfvAO0mpjuIWoKMwqtUXKqjdnYA08YJtmnr/QE

Answer (score 2):

## K5, 2 bytes (function), 5 bytes (program)

### Function

```
+/
```

### Program

```
+/0:`
```

Not sure if K5 was created before or after this challenge was posted. Regardless...THIS IS AWESOME!!

In K5, if you perform arithmetic operations on strings, it converts the characters to their ASCII codes. So this just uses the sum operator `+/` (actually, it's plus + over).

Answer (score 2):

## Matlab/Octave 4 bytes (bonus: 405)

This code is an anonymous function, that does the job, it will take a string, and return the required number.

```
@sum
```

Comment: I am not sure about the `gs2` answer, but at least with the same approach as the Julia answer, I should still write `sum(A)`. I think `sum` alone is not ok (wouldn't even be valid code=).

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript ES6, 41 bytes

```
_=>[..._].map(y=>x+=y.charCodeAt(),x=0)|x
```

*Thanks to @ETHproductions for 2 bytes saved!*

Comment: How about `_=>[..._].map(y=>x+=y.charCodeAt(),x=0)|x`?

Answer (score 2):

## [Gol><>](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/), 4 bytes

```
iEh+
```

Comment: Is it pronounced like 'Golfish?'

Comment: @cat Yes, it's golfish.

Comment: @randomra is that "gol•fish" or "golf•ish"? As in a fish with gol, or something kind of like golf?

Answer (score 2):

## Jolf, 2 bytes

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=dWk&input=SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh)

```
ui
u  sum of
 i  the input string
```

Umm... I don't know what else to say.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
C∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJD4oiRIiwiIiwiSGVsbG8gV29ybGQhIl0=)

#### Explained

```
C∑
C  # char
 ∑ # sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## J (7)

So close, yet so far... Oh well, I guess 7 is decent enough, since this answer also accepts empty strings. (I'm basing my usage of a variable as input on the phrase `from a file, stdin or whatever`)

```
+/a.i.b
```

### Explanation:

```
a.

┌┬┐├┼┤└┴┘│─ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
```

`a.` contains all ASCII chars.

```
   'people' i. 'pow'
0 2 6
```

`x i. y` is similar to python's `[x.index(i) for i in y]`.

```
   a. i. 'Hello World!'
72 101 108 108 111 32 87 111 114 108 100 33
```

Therefor, `a. i. y` converts `y` to an array of its ASCII values

```
   +/1 2 3 4 5 6
21
```

`+/` is like `sum`: `+/1 2 3 4 5 6` means `1+2+3+4+5+6`

```
   +/ a. i. 'Hello World!'
1085
```

The whole thing in action

For the bonus:

```
   b=:'+/a.i.b'
   +/a.i.b
482
```

Not bad, I guess.

```
   b=:'0\{+}/'
   +/a.i.b
478
```

Well, darn.

```
   A=:'+/a.i.A'
   +/a.i.A
449
```

Thanks @algorithmshark

```
    A=:'+/3 u:A'
    +/3 u:A
413
```

Thanks @marinus

Comment: +1 for the great explanation. One little question, where can I best execute J?

Comment: @Knerd From the makers (http://jsoftware.com/) I guess, I don't know any online interpreters. (Fun fact: they have an official console for Android.) http://www.jsoftware.com/download/j801/

Comment: @Synthectica That is cool :D Now I need an Android smartphone :P

Comment: Renaming `b` to `A` results in a score of 449.

Comment: @algorithmshark Oh, right! I'll claim that star for now ;)

Comment: `3 u:` has a lower score (258) than `a.i.` (294)

Comment: @marinus I'll add that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6) 54 <strike>58</strike>

```
alert([].reduce.call(prompt(),(v,c)=>v+c.charCodeAt(0),0))
```

54 bytes thanks to **nderscore**:

```
alert([...prompt()].reduce((v,c)=>v+c.charCodeAt(),0))
```

Comment: Works good, I tried it by now in http://es6fiddle.net

Comment: You could just use Firefox ;)

Comment: I was at work so :D

Comment: 54: `alert([...prompt()].reduce((v,c)=>v+c.charCodeAt(),0))`

Comment: Got it down to 51 now :) `alert([...prompt(x=0)].map(y=>x+=y.charCodeAt())|x)`

Comment: Cool! But I think you should post it as your own answer. It's not my idea, but yous... And it's very clever ;)

Answer (score 1):

## C 32

```
f(char*s){return*s?*s+f(s+1):0;}
```

Comment: `main(int argc,char **argv){return(argc?main(0,&(argv[1])):(**argv?**argv+main(0,argv)+((*argv)++?0:0):0));}` (107 chars) though it ignores the first character for some reason. Also, POSIX exit codes are only 8 bits; in bash, `echo $?`.

Comment: the rules were a little bit broad so i didn't use main. i'll work on something shorter maybe

Comment: @bebe I changed the rules a bit, to make it clear what is needed ;)

Answer (score 1):

### D (function: 60)

Definitely not in it to win it.

Assuming it doesn't need to be a complete program

```d
int c(string i){int s;foreach(e;i){s+=cast(int)e;}return s;}
```

Called like so

```d
void main ()
{
    import std.stdio;
    auto hw = "Hello World!";
    writefln("%s = %d", hw, c(hw));
}
```

Output:

```
Hello World! = 1085
```

### D (program: 133)

Does not count line breaks.

```d
void main(){import std.algorithm,std.stdio;stdin.byLine.map!((a){int s;foreach(e;a){s+=cast(int)e;}return s;}).reduce!"a+b".writeln;}
```

With more whitespace and longer variable names for readability

```d
void main () {
    import std.algorithm, std.stdio;

    stdin.byLine
        .map!((line) {
                int sum;
                foreach (ch; line) {
                    sum += cast(int)ch;
                }
                return sum;
            })
        .reduce!"a+b"
        .writeln;
}
```

To support line breaks in the input, I could either use `byLine(KeepTerminator.yes)` — the correct way, for 20 characters — or append a `'\n'` to my line — which breaks single-line input and may give the wrong sum on Windows because of CRLF, for 18 characters.

Comment: +1 for posting even if you know, that you won't win

Answer (score 1):

### R, <s>35 characters (sum of 3086)</s> 26 bytes (sum of 2305)

```
sum(utf8ToInt(readline()))
```

`readline()` is one character longer than `scan(,"")` but `scan` split the input on spaces by default.

Usage:

```
> sum(utf8ToInt(readline()))
Hello World!
[1] 1085
> sum(utf8ToInt(readline()))
sum(utf8ToInt(readline()))
[1] 2305
> sum(utf8ToInt(readline()))
q/%8hnp>T%y?'wNb\},9krW &D9']K$n;l.3O+tE*$*._B^s!@k\&Cl:EO1zo8sVxEvBxCock_I+2o6 yeX*0Xq:tS^f)!!7=!tk9K<6#/E`ks(D'$z$\6Ac+MT&[s[]_Y(`<g%"w%cW'`c&q)D$0#C$QGf>?A$iawvc,}`9!('`c&q)D$0#C$QGf>?A$iawvc,}`9!(
[1] 14835
```

Answer (score 1):

## Delphi (<strike>87</strike> 83)

```
function x(s:string):int64;var c:char;begin x:=0;for c in s do x:=result+ord(c)end;
```

#### Ungolfed

```
function x(s:string):int64;
var
  c:char;
begin
  x:=0;
  for c in s do
    x:=result+ord(c)
end;
```

Loops through `S` adding the `ord` value of the char to the result. where x==result

### Edits:

Saved 4 characters by switching to int64 and changing the adding to the sum.

Comment: Do you have a free version of Delphi (insert you version here) availiable?

Comment: Hm.. Not really sorry. But I can explain un-golfed what happens where and do some testcases if you want. 
Free pascal has more or less the same syntax so you could do that.

Comment: Ok, I gonna check that out.

Answer (score 1):

## k (8 chars)

```
+/6h$0:0
```

Q translation

```
sum `int$read0 0
```

Bonus value:

```
k)+/6h$0:0
+/6h$0:0
438i
```

Answer (score 1):

### Java 8 - 79 bytes

```
interface C{static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(a[0].chars().sum());}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt), 6 bytes

```
U¬mc x
```

Pretty simple. [Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VaxtYyB4&input=IkhlbGxvIFdvcmxkISI=)

#### How it works

```
U¬mc x  // Implicit: U = input string
U¬      // Split U into chars.
  mc    // Map each item to its char code.
     x  // Sum.
        // Implicit: output last expression
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why didn't you assign `¬` to a negation of some sort?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Because I was in a hurry and just assigned them as I saw need, without planning ahead. I have a set that makes more sense ready to be rolled out, by changing one line of code, but I'm leery about that because it'd invalidate nearly every existing answer.

Comment: That's an easy fix. Add a conditional to the header (e.g., `url/interpreter.html#new=1`); anything without it uses the old character set, and anything with it uses the new character set.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Thanks, I'll consider that.

Answer (score 1):

## [PlatyPar](https://github.com/cyoce/PlatyPar), 2 bytes

```
us
```

[Try it online](https://rawgit.com/cyoce/PlatyPar/master/page.html?code=us)!

`u` generates an array of all charcode values in the input string, and `s` finds their sum.

When run on itself, it returns `232`.

This is similar to Conor's [Jolf answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68536/41042), except that I use a byte to convert the string into an array of character codes (which is implicit in Jolf), whereas he uses a byte to retrieve the input (which is implicit in PlatyPar).

Answer (score 1):

### [JavaScript function golf](http://schas002.github.io/js-function-golf/), 77 bytes

```
var s=i();var x=0;for(var i1=0;i1<sl(s);i1++){x+=schca(s,i1);}console.log(x);
```

I made this for you!

Yes, you got it right, it's my own function golf again. It recently got a string functions update.

The language was created after the challenge, so it's non-competing.

Validity source:

```
>>> var s=i();var x=0;for(var i1=0;i1<sl(s);i1++){x+=schca(s,i1);}console.log(x);
Hello World!
1085
```

Bonus score:

```
>>> var s=i();var x=0;for(var i1=0;i1<sl(s);i1++){x+=schca(s,i1);}console.log(x);
var s=i();var x=0;for(var i1=0;i1<sl(s);i1++){x+=schca(s,i1);}console.log(x);
6276
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Unipants' Golfing Language](https://github.com/schas002/Unipants-Golfing-Language), 8 bytes

```
cIl+I:_o
```

[Try it online!](http://schas002.github.io/Unipants-Golfing-Language/?code=Y0lsK0k6X28&input=SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh)

Returns 660 given its own source code.

### Explanation

```
cIl+I:_o
c        # Create an integer. We need it - you'll see why.
 I       # Input the first character.
  l  :   # While loop.
   +     # Add the character value to the integer. This is
         # why we needed an integer. Otherwise, there would
         # only be 1 item in a stack now, and the "+" op is
         # not defined for this case. In fact, it returns 0
    I    # Input the next character.
      _  # Discard a zero (the zero from the last input,
         # representing the End Of Line).
       o # Output the result.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 113 chars

```
BigInteger C(String s){BigInteger i=BigInteger.ZERO;s.chars().forEach(x->i=i.add(BigInteger.valueOf());return i;}
```

*Note* each character in Java is Unicode 1-4 bytes unsigned integer, using `sum` function would easily overflow.

**Detailed**

```
BigInteger C (String s)
{
    BigInteger i = BigInteger.ZERO;

    s.chars().forEach(x -> i = i.add(BigInteger.valueOf(x));

    return i;
}
```

## Java 8, 57 chars

*ASCII only solution*

```
int C(String s){return s.chars().filter(x->x<128).sum();}
```

**Detailed** [try here](http://ideone.com/FB1d8x)

```
public static int C (String s)
{
    return s
        .chars() // stream the characters
        .filter(x -> x < 128) // filter ASCII (optional)
        .sum(); // return the sum
}
```

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood -- you must work with *at least* ASCII, so there is no reason for you to filter ascii.

Comment: @cat I fixed it now, the solution wouldn't work for unicode since `int` would easily overflow even if you just sum two characters with higher than `2^32 / 2`

Comment: [101 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY5BasMwEEX3OsU0K6nEc4CYZlFIaFaGpFBoyGJsSY5c2TLS2FBCzu5oEWiXjwfv/45mKjr9s7h@DJGhy4w98RVfS@EGNtFSY2B/E@@uPWRuTQQrTxzd0EJSpUhM7BqYg9PQkxue7nwBim1SN7EH@7akYpuwuVJMUuX@@BmqupN/zc1mJj@ZyiqMRk@N@efwe3es1pLWtSq2hKS1rJVaSnH6TWx6DBPjmDfZD9KilasP432ArxC9flmp/PF@Xx4) including `BigInteger` import. Also, your current submission fails to compile (variable referenced in lambda must be final or effectively final)

Comment: [18 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY2xDoMgFAB3vuLVCQb5AdOOprtDh6bDi4DFIhje06Qxfjtl6Hi5XG7GHdvZfIqPbLPD0UJ/iArg5MDZxwlIdYIY2Y@wJ29gQR//7vkCzBOpQ/TgroXaG@nxjZmk0rQtUpVODF9iu@i0sV5rwyFKp51s7jaEBI@Ug7k0qj7Os/wA) for the (unfiltered) ascii-only version

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 37 bytes

```
f=([c,...a])=>c?c.charCodeAt()+f(a):0
```

This uses a handy feature, new in ES6: [destructuring assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). When run, the variable `c` gets set to the first char in the string, and `a` gets set to the rest of the string as an array.

Answer (score 1):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 10 bytes

```
OU@;i)!^(+
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=T1VAO2kpIV4oKw==&input=SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh&speed=20)

This is almost the perfect challenge for Cubix, which can only input one char code at a time. This code expands to the following cube net:

```
    O U
    @ ;
i ) ! ^ ( + . .
. . . . . . . .
    . .
    . .
```

The code is then run, starting at the `i` and facing east. Here's the main loop:

- `i` - input a char code from STDIN and push it to the stack. Pushes -1 on EOF.
- `)` - increment the top item.
- `!` - if the top item is non-zero, skip the next instruction.
- `(` - decrement the top item.
- `+` - add the top two items. Note: the stack has infinite zeroes at the bottom.
- `.` - no-op.

When EOF is reached, the `!` fails, and `^` forces the instruction pointer to move north onto the top face. Then this code is run:

- `;` - pop the top item (currently a 0).
- `U` - turn 180 degrees counter-clockwise. This is used to fit `;O@` on the top face.
- `O` - output the top item (sum of char-codes) as a number.
- `@` - terminate the program.

Comment: I think [`..;Oi?.@/+`](http://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ICAgIC4gLgogICAgOyBPCmkgPyAuIEAgLyArIC4gLgouIC4gLiAuIC4gLiAuIC4KICAgIC4gLgogICAgLiAuCg==&input=SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh&speed=20) works for the same byte count (and less instructions :P )

Comment: @Flp.Tkc That doesn't work on null bytes though, although perhaps "The calculator needs to accept just ASCII encoding" means it won't ever need to

Answer (score 1):

## [Minkolang](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), 6 bytes

```
$o$+N.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/minkolang#@6@Sr6Ltp/f//3@P1JycfIXw/KKcFEUA)

#### Explanation

```
$o         takes all characters from input as chars (the characters are automatically
           converted to their character codes)
$+         sum up all the values
N.         output as number and end program
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÇO
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cLv///8eqTk5@Qrh@UU5KYoA)

**Explanation:**

```python
Ç   # Convert each character in the (implicit) input to its unicode value
 O  # Sum this list of integers
    # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 46 bytes

No PHP answer on this yet, so here's the easy one:

```php
<?=array_sum(array_map(ord,str_split($argn)));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYxbb4IwAEb/SpkFWnHitsSJN6aCizHTLJrpIgodUyAg1LZ4S/zt7va@ty8553w0pNemSUMKIGFBClpgE6wFR5OpNRjhBtB1wKNtnhCxBj/WbR9EKc0FMNvfXYswRk4uz7fob20JRRn7LHHBXE6TSKDfW4xx43rd6XItTGl7Kp9M9TD6cC4lI2YzoFiGuhzCtJGUH8aasIuwWHa7Ky49xY7SS@r2@O6c1fjb0d53j73Mj92Bdp9VwWk9L1bmu7qYrDZYkh5bkoiNYbNa0G0v5shS4Rk61Y6vvUyVBV8s3XfkNQP55iD7M9XzlR22YKXQg6/Pm7bZgRE57P3SxTMk9D/9Ag)

```php
$ echo Hello World!|php -F addascii.php
1085
```

#### More non-competing answers:

**48 bytes**

Iterative:

```php
foreach(str_split($argn)as$s)$x+=ord($s);echo$x;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYzbboIwAEB/pcwCRZy4LXEiXqbAFmOmWTTTxQuwDoSAtNCqaOK3s8sH7O0k5@TQkJadPg0pgF6@S0EXBDufMzSbW6OJYgBNAyzaHxKP@@C3un0GUUoPvAxI7ns4RIznDqNJxNHfQPEYZAos1C7Jv9APGj4OCSyMssw0sRWmtDcXz335NPlcX2t6nC@AZOnyZgxTI6k/TFVuV2G17gy3THiK15KZtO3p3YW02HthH4eFSXDsjNR70gRnf1ltLLM2n20DRRAeuwKP9XGnWdFsN2bIkuEFrpsDrL7OpRVbbZwP5HZ24s1JxAvZxVKmWLBRMeHbS9DrD2DknY64dnV1Af1vvwE)

**51 bytes**

Iterative 2:

```php
while($i<strlen($argn))$x+=ord($argn[$i++]);echo$x;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYtrT4JQAED/yiUvbxOrjURAUqDmXLomSxs@MLoIA3ndq6Cbv51Wfe/j2TknD/NGM/IwB3BX7lOgg2CPCObmjjWe8iqQJICjwzHZEQR@qttnEKX5kTRVGCWIg5GGSZmglPvdeR7Wop6VX3/owkgU17yK/DCDtdo0hUT3wjQfOPTZYKvp5@raVuJyARhLYdcTmKpJ52EmEluAQmc72mDqKV4xZtK3Z3eXrIffa/s0qs3Mj7dj8T6TwRkthe6y6JP5JuAp6lGnSKxMNLkl2V6MOYuFF7iSh7746jAudtfbD87T9vRNRfsL1vOZgrdgt2XCt5dgYAxhtKtOfvvqKRT3v/0G)

**63 bytes**

Recursive:

```php
function f($s,$c=0){return$s?f(substr($s,1),ord($s[0])+$c):$c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY3ZboJAAEV/ZajDMkIF28SKqFSFNsZU00iqjRs6BSHYAZnBreHbqSZ97ttJzrm5SZAUTTMJEgDX6ZaAFvC3HqPS2LH6Q2QAVQU0/M52a@aBW3X/AkKSZKzwM4JZGBPgS5AqELc09JN6LEsJpKYv0WxDWXpTVaTE6deVZtoCyRCjBsRGXng4iK/bv1tkFHuVrwckaTv82RSPw808V/QonQDB0sXFABJjV3kcycwuw3Jl1V1S7jmaC71dwx5VL3GdfpzsQ/fUi3G06ssPcQ2cvWlZm@4bbLz0Ecc9tTgW6YNmraTabkQlS4QXOK91sPzmCDM6W6w@Jbe55e@OPJ6ILhb2yIJaqQffX/222YHh@njASu7qnPS//QU)

**69 bytes**

Using PHP's rarely used <sub>[[citation needed]](http://#)</sub> `array_reduce()` function:

```php
<?=array_reduce(str_split($argn),function($c,$i){return$c+ord($i);});
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYzrUoJAAEZfZckFFiGxmjERlVSocZx0Gp208QK0gjDQgruLt8ZnN@sB@vudc748yi9NK49yAH26IaAFwk3AGRpP7P5QMYGuAxZ/FanPA/Br3T6DmOQFB1b72rV8Sv2jS4N1gQPEOHVZnsYc/X0pWlgQzOOMIIg1GCvfNOAFJRCrGV2j62CeFfNy2epiPSJ5eyIeLXk//FycNSOhUyDZhrwcQGKmlYeRyp0yLFfc7ooJT8lC6qUNZ3R3yurs/eDsuodehhO3r95nNXAMZuXqbNvg41WoCMJjS@CJMWjWSrrjJQzZMjzBRa2D1deJNGfzpfuBvOZGvNmLeCp7WNoqNqyWevDtJWxbHRj7@x3Wzp4hoP/pDw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 2 bytes

```
?⅀
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///f/lFrw///Hqk5OfkK4flFOSmK/3Uzi/7rZhQBAA)

### Explanation

```
?  # Read the full input string
 ⅀ # Sum the whole stack
# Implicit output
```

Comment: [2 bytes](https://tio.run/##y05N///f/lFrw///Hqk5OfkK4flFOSmK/3Uzi/7rZhQBAA "Keg – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

### [W](https://github.com/myu-sername/w), 2 bytes

The Join function also works with numbers.

```
CJ
```

### [W](https://github.com/myu-sername/w), 4 bytes

Terribly golfed answer...

```
C@+R
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$1\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 0.823 bytes

```
S
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJTIiwiSGVsbG8iXQ==)

Comment: imagine my disappointment when I scroll down

Answer (score 0):

## Lua 57

```
a=io.read();b=0;for i=1,#a do b=b+a.byte(a,i)end print(b)
```

Sucks that it's the longest by a long shot, but whatever.

Answer (score 0):

## C# in LINQPad, 28

```
Console.ReadLine().Sum(i=>i)
```

Comment: Will it execute as it is written? See the notes ;)

Comment: Edited and fixed.

Comment: Won't execute, you are missing the `using System;` part.

Comment: Ok, since I'm a LINQPad-addicted, I tend to forget those envrionment things. I decided to edit the title ;) and I think now it works just fine.

Comment: Yeah, should work. For the speed test I gonna add the environment stuff ;)

Answer (score 0):

### C 63

```
main(a,b)char**b;{a+=*b[1];*b[1]++?main(a,b):printf("%d",a-2);}
```

Comment: Compileonline is giving me `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. Any tips?

Comment: @tolos: Yes, it expects input as a command line argument which ideone won;t support

Comment: Is this acutal C? Which IDE/Compiler are you using? Visual Studio 2013 doesn't accept it.

Comment: I compiled with VS2012, yet to install 2013. Note, you actually have to compile as a C Program not as a C++ to make this work

Comment: Ok, didn't know that. I gonna try it as C programm later.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 33

```
$_=<>;$x+=ord for split'';print$x
```

I don't know Perl too well.  I'm sure it can be golfed some more.

Comment: Nice short answer.  Think needs a `chomp` somewhere though, as gives 1095 as answer to Hello World! instead of 1085.

Answer (score 0):

## Cobra - 81

```cobra
class P
    def main
        c,d=Console.readLine,0
        for i in c,d+=i to int
        print d
```

Answer (score 0):

### J (9 chars)

In the REPL, we only need 6 chars:

```
   +/a.i.'Hello World!'
1085
```

To make it a re-usable program, we need to add 3 chars of decoration:

```
   as=: [: +/ a.&i.
   as 'Hello World!'
1085
```

Answer (score 0):

### Common Lisp, 35

```
(reduce'+(read-line):key'char-code)
```

Produces 3053 when given its own code.

Answer (score 0):

## jq, 12 characters

(11 characters code + 1 character command line option.)

```
explode|add
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ bin/jq -R 'explode|add' <<< 'Hello World!'
1085
```

[On-line test](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=explode|add&j=%22Hello%20World!%22) (Passing `-R` through URL is not supported – so input passed as string "Hello World!".)

(CW because `explode` appeared in jq 1.4, released 4 days after this question.)

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 19 bytes

```
0i:1+?!v+!
    ;n~<
```

It does work on Unicode. For example, this correctly outputs 27272
: `⚳ℚ⊻`

[Try it here](http://fishlanguage.com/playground/fkmjSxbFQsTW6Xf7k)

Comment: I don't think that this deserves its own answer, so here's a 14 byte version (split into two lines): `ii:0(7$.+!`, `~n;`. `0` in place of `i` would work, too. An alternate 17 byte version of yours would be `ii:0(?v+!`, `;n~<` (again, in two lines - this time without whitespace on the second)

Answer (score 0):

### Perl, <strike>34</strike> <strike>32</strike> <strike>27</strike> <strike>25</strike> 21+1=22 bytes

Added 2 due to the need for -p flags.  Thanks to @manatwork for the guidance.

```
$a+=ord for/./g;$_=$a
```

Test:

```
echo 'Hello World!' | perl -pe '$a+=ord for/./g;$_=$a'
1085
```

Comment: No need for parenthesis around the statement modifier's expression. And no need to explicitly assign the input to `$_` – after all, that makes it default variable. `$a+=ord for<>=~/./g;print$a`

Comment: As both `-n` and `-p` cost the same 1 character, better use the later and replace `print$a` → `$_=$a`.

Answer (score 0):

### Perl 22

```
s/./$t+=ord$&/eg;say$t
```

sample:

```
perl -nE 's/./$t+=ord$&/eg;say$t'  < <(echo -n Hello\ World\!)
1085
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 144 bytes (sum of 13067)

```
interface S{static void main(String[]A){int I=0;for(char J:new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine().toCharArray())I+=J;System.out.print(I);}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 19 bytes

```
Tr@*ToCharacterCode
```

Test case:

```
Tr@*ToCharacterCode@"Hello World!"
(* 1085 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

## 2, 5 chars / 13 bytes

```
⨭ ᴉ⒨⒞
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter2.html?eval=false&input=asdf&code=%E2%A8%AD%20%E1%B4%89%E2%92%A8%E2%92%9E)</kbd>

Splits and maps the input to its charcodes, then sums the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathcad, 11 "bytes"

[image]

Uses Mathcad's built-in vector summation operator.   As "whatever" is an input method, the user types the word directly into the argument for the function str2vec (which converts a string to a vector of its character codes).

Answer (score 0):

### C++, 131 <s>140</s> bytes

#### Golfed:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
int main(){int a=0;std::string x;getline(std::cin,x);for(int c=0;c<x.length();c++){a=a+(int)x[c];}std::cout<<a;}
```

#### Ungolfed:

```cpp
#include<iostream>

int main(){
    int a = 0;
    std::string x;
    getline(std::cin, x);
    for(int c = 0; c < x.length(); c++){
        a = a + (int) x[c];
    }
    std::cout<<a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Java, 139 Bytes

//takes input from cmd line args

```
class P {public static void main(String a[]){String s=a[0];int v=0;for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){v+=(int)s.charAt(i);}System.out.print(v);}}
```

It's big, but yeah.

Answer (score 0):

## Factor, 3 bytes

```
sum
```

Strings are sequences, arrays of char values. `sum` is basically `0 [ + ] reduce` (or, equivalently, `[ + ] foldl`), so this sums the chars in a string.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathcad, 13 "bytes"

[image]

Uses built-in vector summation operator and string-to-vectorOfCharacterCodes function. Definition operator ":=" entered by single key ":", summation operator by ctl-4.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 37 bytes

```
print(sum([ord(c) for c in input()]))
```

There's a shorter one, but this is possible as well. It converts the string into a list will all the ASCII values of the characters and adds them together using `sum()`.

## Star version, 55 bytes

```
a=sum([ord(c) for c in input()]);print(a);print(chr(a))
```

Now gimme my gold star.

Comment: FWIW: There's an useless whitespace before `for`.

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 31 bytes

```
#(reduce +(map int(read-line)))
```

Really straightforward. Gets its input from stdin, works with Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

### [Hoon](https://github.com/urbit/urbit), 18 bytes

```
|*
*
(roll +< add)
```

This is a wet gate, so that I don't have to specify `tape` instead of `*`. This has the added bonus of it being fully generic, so it could actually accept `(list @ud)` too. Wet gates typecheck at the call site, instead of definition.

`+<` is the sample of the gate, indexed into the sample with tree navigation syntax because it's shorter than naming the function arguments. `|*(a/* a)` is longer than `|*(* +<)`.

```
> %.  "Hello World!"
  |*
  *
  (roll +< add)
b=1.085
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work correctly as-is with unicode. Urbit's string literals are lists of UTF8 chars. You can use `++tuba` to convert it to UTF32, though.

```
> %.  "⚳ℚ⊻"
  |*
  *
  (roll +< add)
b=1.622

> %.  (tuba "⚳ℚ⊻")
  |*
  *
  (roll +< add)
b=27.272
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pushy, 2 bytes

```
S#
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/pushy#@x@s/P//fyWP1JycfIXw/KKcFEUlAA)

Input is automatically converted to charcodes and placed on the stack. `S` sums the stack, and `#` prints it.

Answer (score 0):

## Brainfuck - 15 Bytes

```
,[>,]<[[<+>-]<]
```

[Try it here](https://fatiherikli.github.io/brainfuck-visualizer/#LFs+LF08W1s8Kz4tXTxdIQ==) (You have to click the box marked "!")

Put your input after the exclamation point. (not necessary but allows easy EOF.)

### What it does

```
,[>,]     take input as characters in separate cells until input has ended (automatically in ascii)
<         go to the last character
[         infinite loop
[<+>-]    add the last character and the character before it and save it as the last character
<]        go back to the last character and then do the infinite loop again
```

Unfortunately, it exits with an out of memory error and does not print the output, but that wasn't part of the challenge. If you want to see the output, read the tape. It also only goes up to 255 on this interpreter. (if anyone knows an interpreter with larger cells that exits on error, that would be great)

Comment: The counter overflows if you input something such as `Hello World!`...

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pF`, 15 bytes

Under the rules in place at the time of this challenge, I believe it would have been +3 for the command line flags, giving a score of 18.

```perl
map$\+=ord,@F}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83sUAlRts2vyhFx8Gttvr/f4/UnJx8hfD8opwUxX/5BSWZ@XnF/3UL3AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 61 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S N
S _Duplicate_top][S N
S _Duplicate_top][T N
T   S _Read_STDIN_as_character][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input][S N
S _Duplicate][S S S T   S T S N
_Push_10][T S S T   _Subtract][N
T   S S N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_PRINT][T    S S S _Add][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_PRINT][S N
N
_Discard_newline][T N
S T _Output_top_as_integer]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

Since Whitespace inputs one character at a time, the input should contain a trailing newline so it knows when to stop reading characters and the input is done.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgYsLiBXABCcXpwInJyeIo6AAZCoA@WBBMAOkCqQYTHMCVf//75Gak5OvEJ5flJOiyAUA) (with raw spaces, tabs, and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Integer s = 0
Start LOOP:
  Integer c = Read STDIN as character
  If(c == 10) // c == '\n'
    Call function PRINT
  s = s + c
  Go to next iteration of LOOP

function PRINT:
  Discard the top of the stack (the 10 / newline)
  Print s as integer to STDOUT
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 14 bytes

```cs
s=>s.Sum(x=>x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9WmpdsU1xSlJmXrpOZV2KnkKZg@7/Y1q5YL7g0V6PC1q5C8781V3hRZkmqT2ZeqkaahpJHak5OvkJ4flFOiqKSpqb1fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## Unexpended Sinclair ZX80 - 65 tokenized BASIC bytes

```
 1 INPUT A$
 2 LET A=0
 3 IF A$="" THEN GO TO 7
 4 LET A=A+CODE(A$)
 5 LET A$=TL$(A$)
 6 GO TO 3
 7 PRINT A
```

There are a few caveats, without `POKE`ing some (or one, I don't recall) memory location(s), all maths is done via 16-bit signed integers, so the range is -32768 to +32767, so any string entered that is too long will overflow the `VAR` stack and break the program. Also, the ZX80 character set is not ASCII compatible and there is no exclamation mark, so `HELLO WORLD` (as there are no lower-case characters by default either) is `494` - [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZX80_character_set).

BASIC does not update the screen whilst doing calculations and such, so after entering the string it will take some time to work out where nothing will be displayed. Your original string entered in the `A$` variable will not show.

[image: Sinclair ZX80 Calculator that adds char values]

Answer (score 0):

## [Ahead](https://github.com/ajc2/ahead), 5 bytes

```
SK+O@

S      slurp input
 K+    reduce stack by summing
   O   output sum
    @  end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xITUz5/z/YW9vf4f9/j9ScnHyF8PyinBRFAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 22 bytes

`(String) -> Int` lambda.

```
{it.sumBy{it.toInt()}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY2xCgIxEET7fMV4VVLoBxyoYKVgZ2EdvKiLexuJe6Ic@faYgN0w83jziMok5e0Zl7tPr2nsYU@aSG4Oyw0OoliXmXRVp923BY21tC7ncp0EoyexDrNBc2j4VB4p@OFIEuqw7dF1MHhWpbLY/4ttpHMwuewDc8Q5Jh4WPw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 10 bytes (Self-sum: 703)

```
iul1)?@+2?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z@zNMdQ095B28j@/3@P1Jyc/BiF8PyinBRFAA)

It has a limit on how long of a string it can handle. For a version that can handle any length string:

```
/l͍:i0< /~~@
R1-:0≮?/:}}:{%3s}+}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/18/52yvVaaBjYJ@XZ0DV5ChrpWBzZkd9vpWtbVW1arGxbXatf//e6Tm5OTHKITnF@WkKAIA) (Self-sum: 3937)

In both cases spaces need to be escaped in order to be read as a single input. The first one works by unconcatening the string and iteratively adding each character together until only a single value is left (printing it).

The second uses an index pointer and extracts one character at a time, adding it to a running total (requiring more in the way of setup and stack manipulation).

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-mx`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 1 byte

```
c
```

[Try it!](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW14&code=Yw&input=WyJIIiwiZSIsImwiLCJsIiwibyIsIiAiLCJXIiwibyIsInIiLCJsIiwiZCIsIiEiXQoKLW14)

---

If the input cannot be an array of chars, then this can be done in 3 bytes:

```
¬xc
```

[Try it!](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=rHhj&input=IkhlbGxvIFdvcmxkISIKCg)

Answer (score 0):

### [@](https://github.com/gemdude46/atLang/blob/master/%40docs.txt), 4 bytes

Seems like a perfect task for @.

```
Σš
```

Explanation

```
Σ  Summation of
 š a one-line input
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 6 bytes (own code sum: 577)

```
({{}})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X6O6urZW8/9/j9ScnHyF8PyinBTF/7qJAA)

Seems to be a good challenge for Brain-Flak.

**Explanation:**

```
 {  }   while top of Stack is not 0, calculate sum of
  {}    pop value
(    )  push calculated sum
        implicitly output the Stack
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 35 bytes

The fact that they aren't doing this in Wren is a perfect chance for me.

```
Fn.new{|x|x.bytes.reduce{|a,i|a+i}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcuxCoAgEADQXzEno7g/aI32hmbTC4TL4LIs1G83evuLjL7emsV2eSMGUUcPHmPKT35gfQOewGgvgynr3mXduVLq/J4Bd4jsAqo/gtFESk5IdIjlYLKNbNv6AQ)

### Explanation

```
Fn.new{|x|                        } // New anonymous function with parameter x
          x.bytes                   // Convert x to its bytecode forms
                 .reduce{|a,i|a+i}  // Sum this bytecode form
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 3 bytes

```
sCM
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v9jZ9/9/JY/UnJx8hfD8opwURSUA)

Alternatively, `smC` works as well.

**Explanation:**

```
    # implicit output
s   # sum(                )
  M #     map(   ,       )
 C  #         ord
    #             input()   -> implicit input
```

Answer (score 0):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 2 bytes

```
+/
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs9LW5+JKi1bySM3JyVcIzy/KSVFUigUASq4Grg==)

In K, a string is basically a list of ASCII char codes, so just the sum adverb will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 58 bytes

```go
func f(b[]byte)(s int){for _,e:=range b{s+=int(e)}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BzoLE5OzE9FSF3MTMPK7M3IL8ohI9pbTcEqWlpSVpuhY3rdJK85IV0jSSomOTKktSNTWKFTLzSjSr0_KLFOJ1Uq1sixLzgNqTqou1bYESGqmatVxFqSWlRXm1UBPaSyoLUhWcbCEGcIHNA9mmoalQzRVQBNSUk6eRpuGkoeSRmpOTrxCeX5SToqikqamJIptAvkMSQGZBnbNgAYQGAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 10 bytes

```
*.ords.sum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfSy@/KKVYr7g097@1QnFipUKahrpHak5OvkJ4flFOiqK65n8A)

The `ords` string method conveniently returns a list of the ordinal values of the characters.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `SB`, 0 bytes

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faFm0UrCTUuyCpaUlaboWC5YUJyUXwzhrPFJzcvIVwvOLclIUIWIA)

Or, **2 bytes** flagless:

```
CS
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWi5yDlxQnJRdDuQvWeKTm5OQrhOcX5aQoQsQA)