# Find max sequence length

Tags: code-golf, string

Assume we have a string, and we want to find the maximum repeated sequence of every letter.

For example, given the sample input:

```
"acbaabbbaaaaacc"
```

Output for the sample input can be:

```
a=5
c=2
b=3
```

Rules:

- Your code can be function or a program - for you to choose
- Input can be by stdin, file or function parameter
- The output should contain only characters that appear in the input
- Input max length is 1024
- The output order does not matter, but it has to be printed in the form [char]=[maximum repeated sequence][delimiter]
- The string can contain any character

The competition ends on Thursday 3rd at 23:59 UTC.

Comment: Is there a maximum to the length of the input string?

Comment: Does the output have to be exactly as given? Can we say 0 for letters that don't appear? Will every letter up to the highest letter appear at least once?

Comment: Please clarify if the output has to be formatted exactly as exemplified in your question. At least 10 of the current 16 answers use a different format, three others present two different versions.

Comment: Does You'r string contain only letters or it may have some special character and numbers.

Comment: shall program handle `\0` character as normal character?

Comment: I had this exact problem in a lab in first year of college :). Except not code golf

Comment: @Cruncher: Back when I graded homework in uni I wouldn't have punished anyone for golfing ;-) (but Pascal doesn't golf that well)

Comment: @Joey You probably should punish for golfing. By you condoning it, I'm going to end up seeing `l:S_&{'=L{2$+_S\#)}g,(N}/` in production systems! And I will curse your name.

Comment: Does this count? :) http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=char+%22acbaabbbaaaaacc%22+frequency

Answer (score 22):

## 8086 machine code, <strike>82</strike> 80

Contents of the `x.com` file:

```
B7 3D 89 DF B1 80 F3 AA 0D 0A 24 B4 01 CD 21 42
38 D8 74 F7 38 17 77 02 88 17 88 C3 31 D2 3C 0D
75 E9 BF 21 3D B1 5E 31 C0 F3 AE E3 EE 4F BB 04
01 8A 05 D4 0A 86 E0 0D 30 30 89 47 02 3C 30 77
04 88 67 03 43 89 3F 89 DA B4 09 CD 21 47 EB D7
```

It only supports repetitions of up to 99 characters.

Source code (served as input for the `debug.com` assembler), with comments!

```
a
    mov bh, 3d         ; storage of 128 bytes at address 3d00
    mov di, bx
    mov cl, 80
    rep stosb          ; zero the array
    db 0d 0a 24
; 10b
    mov ah, 1
    int 21             ; input a char
    inc dx             ; calculate the run length
    cmp al, bl         ; is it a repeated character?
    je  10b
    cmp [bx], dl       ; is the new run length greater than previous?
    ja  11a
    mov [bx], dl       ; store the new run length
; 11a
    mov bl, al         ; remember current repeating character
    xor dx, dx         ; initialize run length to 0
    cmp al, d          ; end of input?
    jne 10b            ; no - repeat
    mov di, 3d21       ; start printing run lengths with char 21
    mov cl, 5e         ; num of iterations = num of printable characters
; 127
    xor ax, ax
    repe scasb         ; look for a nonzero run length
    jcxz 11b           ; no nonzero length - exit
    dec di
    mov bx, 104        ; address of output string
    mov al, [di]       ; read the run length
    aam                ; convert to decimal
    xchg al, ah
    or  ax, 3030
    mov [bx+2], ax
    cmp al, 30         ; was it less than 10?
    ja  145
    mov [bx+3], ah     ; output only one digit
    inc bx             ; adjust for shorter string
; 145
    mov [bx], di       ; store "x=" into output string
    mov dx, bx         ; print it
    mov ah, 9
    int 21
    inc di
    jmp 127            ; repeat
; 150

rcx 50
n my.com
w
q
```

Here are some golfing techniques used here that I think were fun:

- array's address is `3d00`, where `3d` is the ascii-code for `=`. This way, the address for array's entry for character `x` is `3d78`. When interpreted as a 2-character string, it's `x=`.
- Output buffer is at address `104`; it overwrites initialization code that is no longer needed. End-of-line sequence `0D 0A 24` is executed as harmless code.
- The `aam` instruction here doesn't provide any golfing, though it could...
- Writing the number twice, first assuming it's greater than 10, and then correcting if it's smaller.
- Exit instruction is at an obscure address `11b`, which contains the needed machine code `C3` by luck.

Comment: Interesting approach. However, with a limitation of 99 repetitions, it wouldn't handle cases where the input of 1024 aaaa's is supplied.

Answer (score 14):

## CJam, <s>27</s> <s>26</s> 25 bytes

```
l:S_&{'=L{2$+_S\#)}g,(N}/
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

#### Example

```
$ cjam maxseq.cjam <<< "acbaabbbaaaaacc"
a=5
c=2
b=3
```

#### How it works

```
l:S       " Read one line from STDIN and store the result in “S”.                   ";
_&        " Intersect the string with itself to remove duplicate characters.        ";
{         " For each unique character “C” in “S”:                                   ";
  '=L     " Push '=' and ''.                                                        ";
  {       "                                                                         ";
    2$+_  " Append “C” and duplicate.                                               ";
    S\#)  " Get the index of the modified string in “S” and increment it.           ";
  }g      " If the result is positive, there is a match; repeat the loop.           ";
  ,       " Retrieve the length of the string.                                      ";
  (       " Decrement to obtain the highest value that did result in a match.       ";
  N       " Push a linefeed.                                                        ";
}/        "                                                                         ";
```

Answer (score 9):

### J - 52 bytes

Well, a simple approach again.

```
f=:([,'=',m=:":@<:@#@[`(]m~[,{.@[)@.(+./@E.))"0 1~~.
```

Explanation:

```
f=:([,'=',m=:":@<:@#@[`(]m~[,{.@[)@.(+./@E.))"0 1~~.
                                                 ~~. Create a set of the input and apply it as the left argument to the following.
   ([,'=',m=:":@<:@#@[`(]m~[,{.@[)@.(+./@E.))"0 1    The function that does the work
                                             "0 1    Apply every element from the left argument (letters) with the whole right argument (text).
                                  @.(+./@E.)         Check if the left string is in right string.
                       (]m~[,{.@[)                   If yes, add one letter to the left string and recurse.
             ":@<:@#@[                               If not, return (length of the left string - 1), stringified.
    [,'=',                                           Append it to the letter + '='
```

Example:

```
   f 'acbaabbbaaaaacc'
a=5
c=2
b=3
   f 'aaaabaa'
a=4
b=1
```

If free-form output is allowed (as in many other answers), I have a **45 bytes** version too. These boxes represent a list of boxes (yes, they're printed like that, although SE's line-height breaks them).

```
   f=:([;m=:<:@#@[`(]m~[,{.@[)@.(+./@E.))"0 1~~.
   f 'acbaabbbaaaaacc'
┌─┬─┐
│a│5│
├─┼─┤
│c│2│
├─┼─┤
│b│3│
└─┴─┘
   f 'aaaabaabba'
┌─┬─┐
│a│4│
├─┼─┤
│b│2│
└─┴─┘
```

Answer (score 8):

## Ruby, 72

```rb
(a=$*[0]).chars.uniq.map{|b|puts [b,a.scan(/#{b}+/).map(&:size).max]*?=}
```

This takes input from command line arguments and outputs to stdout.

Comment: `chars` is a bit shorter than `split("")`.

Comment: @Ventero I tried that, but `chars` gives an enumerator rather than an array. I am in 1.9.3, so is it a 2.0 thing?

Comment: Yeah, in 2.0 `chars` returns an array.

Comment: It may be stretching the rules a bit, but perhaps use `p` instead of `puts`?

Comment: Why not take input from stdin? `gets` is shorter than `$*[0]` . Besides you can then skip the assignment to `a` and use `$_` instead. Should save you at least 4 chars in total.

Comment: @daniero the problem is that `gets` inserts a line break at the end of the input which is counted as a character.

Comment: I see. Although that makes it less pretty, I can't see that it would break any rules tho.

Answer (score 7):

## GolfScript, 26 bytes

```
:s.&{61{2$=}s%1,/$-1=,n+}%
```

[Try it online.](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=IyBDYW5uZWQgdGVzdCBpbnB1dDoKOyJhY2JhYWJiYmFhYWFhY2MiCgojIEFjdHVhbCBwcm9ncmFtIGNvZGU6CjpzLiZ7NjF7MiQ9fXMlMSwvJC0xPSxuK30l)

Explanation:

- `:s` saves the input string in the variable `s` for later use.
- `.&` extracts the unique characters in the input, which the rest of the code in the `{ }%` loop then iterates over.
- `61` pushes the number 61 (ASCII code for an equals sign) on top of the current character on the stack, to act as an output delimiter.
- `{2$=}s%` takes the string `s` and replaces its characters with a 1 if they equal the current character being iterated over, or 0 if they don't.  (It also leaves the current character on the stack for output.)
- `1,/` takes this string of ones and zeros, and splits it at zeros.
- `$` sorts the resulting substrings, `-1=` extracts the last substring (which, since they all consist of repetitions of the same character, is the longest), and `,` returns the length of this substring.
- `n+` stringifies the length and appends a newline to it.

Ps. If the equals signs in the output are optional, the `61` can be omitted (and the `2$` replaced by `1$`), for a total length of **24 bytes**:

```
:s.&{{1$=}s%1,/$-1=,n+}%
```

Comment: You can save the swap if you push the `61` first: `:s.&{61{2$=}s%1,/$-1=,n+}%`.

Answer (score 6):

### CoffeeScript, 109 bytes

I like regex.

```
f=(s)->a={};a[t[0]]=t.length for t in s.match(/((.)\2*)(?!.*\1)/g).reverse();(k+'='+v for k,v of a).join '\n'
```

Here is the compiled JavaScript you can try in your browser's console

```
f = function(s) {
  var a, t, _i, _len, _ref;
  a = {};
  _ref = s.match(/((.)\2*)(?!.*\1)/g).reverse();
  for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    t = _ref[_i];
    a[t[0]] = t.length;
  }
  return a;
};
```

Then you can call

```
f("acbaabbbaaaaacc")
```

to get

```
c=2
a=5
b=3
```

Comment: This seems to generate incorrect results for input like `aaaabaa`.

Comment: @Ventero you're right, there are two problems. one is easily fixed, but I need to think about the other.

Comment: @Ventero fixed.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 69 bytes

```python
s=input()
for c in set(s):
 i=0
 while-~i*c in s:i+=1
 print(c,'=',i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JclBCoAgEEDRvaeYnVoGRTvBw@hgOBAqakSbrm5Cf/E2Pz8tpLj3Xg3FfDUh2ZEKIFCE6puoUjMgszK4A51@eWn6n6bZbAxyodgEKm64Itm7RWetc4MR4gc)

Even golfed Python can be very readable. I think this code is fully idiomatic except for the `-~i` for `i+1` and the single-letter variables. Thanks to pxeger for saving 1 byte.

Example runs:

```python
>>> helloworld
e = 1
d = 1
h = 1
l = 2
o = 1
r = 1
w = 1
>>> acbaabbbaaaaacc
a = 5
c = 2
b = 3
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution

Comment: if you change set(s) to just s I think it still meets the requirements. Nowhere does it say each char must be printed only once.

Comment: @Cruncher I agree the OP doesn't specify each letter once, but the other Python answers seem to assume it, so I'll stick with that to be comparable. Though output formats are still inconsistent. I do wish the OP had responded to the requests to clarify.

Comment: You can change `for c in set(s)` to `for c in{*s}` for -2 bytes

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing It looks like this answer actually predates the introduction of set unpacking in Python 3.5, so I'll keep it as is.

Comment: 69 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JclBCoAgEEDRvaeYnVoGRTvBw@hgOBAqakSbrm5Cf/E2Pz8tpLj3Xg3FfDUh2ZEKIFCE6puoUjMgszK4A51@eWn6n6bZbAxyodgEKm64Itm7RWetc4MR4gc "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyth](http://ideone.com/xBaxnq), 24 <strike>25</strike> <strike>26</strike> (or 29)

```
=ZwFY{Z=bkW'bZ~bY)p(Yltb
```

Test can be done here: [link](http://ideone.com/fork/lSBjJG)

Outputs in the format:

```
('a', 5)
('c', 2)
('b', 3)
```

Explanation:

```
=Zw              Store one line of stdin in Z
FY{Z             For Y in set(Z):
=bk              b=''
W'bZ             while b in Z:
~bY              b+=Y
)                end while
p(Yltb           print (Y, len(b)-1)
```

Python:

```
k=""
Z=copy(input())
for Y in set(Z):
 b=copy(k)
 while (b in Z):
  b+=Y
 print(_tuple(Y,len(tail(b))))
```

For proper (a=5) output, use:

```
=ZwFY{Z=bkW'bZ~bY)p++Y"="`ltb
```

29 characters

Comment: Seems like you had the exact same idea. Have a +1 for that.

Comment: @TheRare yeah, it seems like a very good way to do it.

Comment: Not really related to your algorithm, but the python output is confusing, because `k=''` is defined elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I'll work on improving it. I'll edit it too.

Answer (score 5):

## C, <strike>126</strike> <strike>125</strike> 119 bytes

```
l,n,c[256];main(p){while(~(p=getchar()))n*=p==l,c[l=p]=c[p]>++n?c[p]:n;for(l=256;--l;)c[l]&&printf("%c=%d\n",l,c[l]);}
```

Running:

```
$ gcc seq.c 2>& /dev/null
$ echo -n 'acbaabbbaaaaacc' | ./a.out
c=2
b=3
a=5
```

Comment: You could replace `getchar()>0` by `~getchar()` like in [this answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/30232/25315)

Comment: @anatolyg Is EOF guaranteed to be exactly -1? I thought it was only specifically defined as being <0.

Comment: I think -1 is common enough (i.e. Windows and linux) so you can assume it for Code Golf. For production code, `less than zero` is perfectly OK, but `== EOF` is more clear.

Comment: @anatolyg Sure, and actually I guess per the spec EOF apparently isn't even guaranteed to be <0 - it *could* also be, for example, 256. So I'll just save the single byte. :)

Comment: `EOF` is guaranteed to be negative, and -1 is used even if `char` is signed; see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7059384/509868)

Comment: @anatolyg Thanks! That bit was vague from the resources I could find online, so it's good to know the actual spec section. Also, I've put in way more sequence point abuse to cut it down even more. :)

Answer (score 4):

### *Mathematica*, <s>74</s> <s>72</s> 69

```
Print[#[[1,1]],"=",Max[Tr/@(#^0)]]&/@Split@Characters@#~GatherBy~Max&

% @ "acbaabbbaaaaacc"
```

> ```
> a=5
> c=2
> b=3
> ```

Not very good but strings are not *Mathematica*'s best area.  Getting better though. :-)

Comment: This is pretty impressive golfing (saying this after having tried it myself ...)

Comment: v10, not a full solution: `First@*MaximalBy[Length] /@ GroupBy[First]@Split@Characters[#] &`  At least it's pretty straightforward and readable.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks!  What's the difference between `GroupBy` and `GatherBy`?

Comment: The main difference is that `GroupBy` returns an `Association`.  I haven't studied the other differences in detail yet.  http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html  You can try it in the [cloud](http://www.wolframcloud.com/) with a free account (that's how I'm playing with these).

Answer (score 3):

## *C#* (LinQPad)

### 146

This is tsavino's answer but shorter. Here, I used `Distinct()` instead of `GroupBy(c=>c)`. Also the curly braces from the `foreach-loop` are left out:

```
void v(string i){foreach(var c in i.Distinct())Console.WriteLine(c+"="+(from Match m in Regex.Matches(i,"["+c+"]+")select m.Value.Length).Max());}
```

---

### 136

I tried using a `lambda expression` instead of the normal query syntax but since I needed a `Cast<Match>` first, the code became 1 character longer... Anyhow, since it can be executed in LinQPad, you can use `Dump()` instead of `Console.WriteLine()`:

```
void v(string i){foreach(var c in i.Distinct())(c+"="+(from Match m in Regex.Matches(i,"["+c+"]+")select m.Value.Length).Max()).Dump();}
```

---

Further study of the code got me thinking about the `Max()`. This function also accepts a `Func`. This way I could skip the `Select` part when using the lambda epxression:

```
void v(string i){foreach(var c in i.Distinct())(c+"="+Regex.Matches(i,"["+c+"]+").Cast<Match>().Max(m=>m.Value.Length)).Dump();}
```

Thus, final result:

## *128*

**Update:**

Thanks to the tip from Dan Puzey, I was able to save another 6 characters:

```
void v(string i){i.Distinct().Select(c=>c+"="+Regex.Matches(i,"["+c+"]+").Cast<Match>().Max(m=>m‌​.Value.Length)).Dump();}
```

Length:

## 122

Comment: Thank you for your improvements, I didn't know about the trick with the .Dump() in LinqPad. To be honest, I developed the code in Visual Studio and copied it to LinqPad to save some characters because LinqPad doesn't need a main method.

Comment: Thanks! I also just got to know the `Dump()` method recently, saves you 10+ chars every time :) The curly braces was easy and the rest was a bit of braincracking :D

Comment: If you're happy to use LinqPad's `IEnumerable` display style you can save another 8 chars, with this as your body: `i.Distinct().Select(c=>c+"="+Regex.Matches(i,"["+c+"]+").Cast<Match>().Max(m=>m.Value.Length)).Dump();`

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 58

```
h={}
gets.scan(/(.)\1*/){h[$1]=[h[$1]||0,$&.size].max}
p h
```

Takes input from STDIN, outputs it to STDOUT in the form `{"a"=>5, "c"=>2, "b"=>3}`

Answer (score 2):

## C# in LINQPad - 159 Bytes

Well, at least I beat T-SQL ;P Won't beat anyone else, but I thought I'd share it anyway.

```
void v(string i){foreach(var c in i.GroupBy(c=>c)){Console.WriteLine(c.Key+"="+(from Match m in Regex.Matches(i,"["+c.Key+"]+")select m.Value.Length).Max());}}
```

Usage:

```
v("acbaabbbaaaaacc");
```

Suggestions are always welcome!

Comment: Great answer! I've got some suggestions but that was too long for a comment so [click here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32541/find-max-sequence-length/32666#32666) for my answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell <s>80</s> <s>77</s> 72

```
$x=$args;[char[]]"$x"|sort -u|%{"$_="+($x-split"[^$_]"|sort)[-1].length}
```

You need to run it on console...

Comment: `$x` is superfluous. You're three byte shorter not using it. Also `sort -u` suffices. There is rarely a need of spelling out the complete parameter names. This will, however, fail for certain characters due to the unescaped use in the regex. Depending on how »The string can contain any character« is to be understood, this could be a problem.

Comment: @Joey thanks for the tip on sort -u, however regarding the $x I couldn't get it to work like `[char[]]"$args"|sort -u|%{"$_="+($args-split"[^$_]"|sort)[-1].length}`, it seems the second $args comes empty... –  darkajax 17 mins ago

Comment: Eep, yes. Sorry. That's because it's in a script block, which has its own arguments (the `$args` there is no longer the one of the script).

Answer (score 2):

## Perl - 65 <strike>71</strike> <strike>76</strike> characters

My first code golf!

For each answer, copy to golf.pl and run as:

```
echo acbaabbbaaaaacc | perl golf.pl
```

My shortest solution prints each character as many times as it appears, since that is not prohibited by the rules.

```
$_=$i=<>;for(/./g){$l=length((sort$i=~/$_*/g)[-1]);print"$_=$l
"}
```

My next-shortest solution (85 <strike>90</strike> characters) only prints each character once:

```
<>=~s/((.)\2*)(?{$l=length$1;$h{$2}=$l if$l>$h{$2}})//rg;print"$_=$h{$_}
"for keys %h
```

Answer (score 1):

## F# - 106

```
let f s=
 let m=ref(Map.ofList[for c in 'a'..'z'->c,0])
 String.iter(fun c->m:=(!m).Add(c,(!m).[c]+1))s;m
```

In FSI, calling

```
f "acbaabbbaaaaacc"
```

gives

```
val it : Map<char,int> ref =
  {contents =
    map
      [('a', 8); ('b', 4); ('c', 3); ('d', 0); ('e', 0); ('f', 0); ('g', 0);
       ('h', 0); ('i', 0); ...];}
```

However, to print it without the extra information, call it like this:

```
f "acbaabbbaaaaacc" |> (!) |> Map.filter (fun _ n -> n > 0)
```

which gives

```
val it : Map<char,int> = map [('a', 8); ('b', 4); ('c', 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

### T-SQL (2012) <strike>189</strike> 171

Edit: removed `ORDER BY` because rules allow any output order.

Takes input from a CHAR variable, `@a`, and uses a [recursive CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) to create a row for each character in the string and figures out sequential occurrences.

After that, it's a simple `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` with consideration for the order of the output.

[Try it out](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/19777/0) on SQL Fiddle.

```
WITH x AS(
    SELECT @a i,''c,''d,0r,1n
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT i,SUBSTRING(i,n,1),c,IIF(d=c,r+1,1),n+1
    FROM x
    WHERE n<LEN(i)+2
)
SELECT d+'='+LTRIM(MAX(r))
FROM x
WHERE n>2
GROUP BY d
```

Assigning the variable:

```
DECLARE @a CHAR(99) = 'acbaabbbaaaaacc';
```

Sample output:

```
a=5
c=2
b=3
```

Comment: I don't think I've seen a SQL solution here before. Interesting.

Comment: consider the `str`, function instead of `ltrim`. You can also name your variable `@` to save a char. This allows you to lose the `i` variable in the rcte. I think you can shave quite a few chars that way. You might also be able to rewrite the query with using a windowing function like sum over rows preceding or lag. I haven't quite formed how yet mind you.

Comment: @MichaelB thanks for the advice. The trouble I have with str() is that it outputs a bunch of extra spaces. I will definitely start using @ as a variable!

Comment: It's true that `str` always outputs 10 characters, but this is golfing :P

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell - 113 <del>120</del> bytes

```hs
import Data.List
main=interact$show.map(\s@(c:_)->(c,length s)).sort.nubBy(\(a:_)(b:_)->a==b).reverse.sort.group
```

Tested with

```hs
$ printf "acbaabbbaaaaacc" | ./sl
[('a',5),('b',3),('c',2)]
```

Comment: You can use the `.` (compose) function to avoid creating a lambda where the parameter only appears after the end of a chain of `$` connected functions. To do this, simply change all the `$`s to `.`s (example: `(\i->reverse$sort$group i)` turns into `reverse.sort.group`.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 116 bytes

```
y=x=prompt();while(y)r=RegExp(y[0]+'+','g'),alert(y[0]+'='+x.match(r).sort().reverse()[0].length),y=y.replace(r,'')
```

Sample output:

```
lollolllollollllollolllooollo
l=4
o=3

acbaabbbaaaaacc
a=5
c=2
b=3

helloworld
h=1
e=1
l=2
o=1
w=1
r=1
d=1
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript - 91

```javascript
for(i=0,s=(t=prompt()).match(/(.)\1*/g);c=s[i++];)t.match(c+c[0])||alert(c[0]+'='+c.length)
```

**EDIT:** My first solution obeys the rules, but it prints several times single char occurrences like `abab` => `a=1,b=1,a=1,b=1` so I came out with this (**101** chars), for those not satisfied with my first one:

```javascript
for(i=0,s=(t=prompt()).match(/((.)\2*)(?!.*\1)/g);c=s[i++];)t.match(c+c[0])||alert(c[0]+'='+c.length)
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript [83 bytes]

```
prompt().match(/(.)\1*/g).sort().reduce(function(a,b){return a[b[0]]=b.length,a},{})
```

<sup>Run this code in the browser console.</sup>

For input "`acbaabbbaaaaacc`" the console should output "`Object {a: 5, b: 3, c: 2}`".

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
ŒriƇṀj”=ʋⱮQY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opKLMY@0PdzZkPWqYa3uq@9HGdYGR////V0pMTkpMTEoCEkCQnKwEAA)

-2 bytes thanks to Unrelated String!

[8 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opKLMY@0PdzacnP5o47rA/4fbj056uHPG//9KiclJiYlJSUACCJKTlQA) to output as a list of pairs

### How it works

```
ŒriƇṀj”=ʋⱮQY - Main link. Takes a string S on the left
        ʋ    - Group the previous 4 links into a dyad f(S, C):
Œr           -   Run-length encode S
   Ƈ         -   For each sublist in rle(S), keep it if:
  i          -     It contains C
    Ṁ        -   Maximum
                 As all elements are in the form [C, n] for integers n,
                 Python considers the maximum as the greatest n
     j”=     -   Join with "="; Yields [C, "=", n]
          Q  - Get the unique characters of S
         Ɱ   - For each unique character C in S, yield f(C, S)
           Y - Join by newlines and output
```

Comment: I think the `Ṫṭ` can be removed: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opKLMY@0PdzZkPWqYa8t1ePmjjesCI////6@UmJyUmJiUBCSAIDlZCQA "Jelly – Try It Online")

Comment: @UnrelatedString Of course! The dangers of golfing at 1 in the morning :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 18 bytes

```
mȯJ'=§eo;←osL►Lk←g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/fEei9120PLU/OtH7VNyC/2eTRtl082kJn@//9/pcTkpMTEpCQgAQTJyUoA)

11 bytes if we ignore the exact input format and display as a list of pairs instead.

Comment: [16 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219914/95126): your turn now!

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 16 bytes

```
mS:(:'=s▲`mg¹#)U
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/PzfYSsNK3bb40bRNCbnph3Yqa4b@//8/MTkpMTEpCUiggORkAA)

**Explanation:**

```
m              U    # for each of the unique elements of the input
 S:                 # prepend the element to
   (:'=       )     # '=' prepended to
        ▲           # the maximum of
             #      # the number of times it occurs in 
         `mg¹       # each group of identical items in the input,
       s            # converted into a string
```

I saw that [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime) had answered this in [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), so I had to have a go too...

Comment: I'm surprised Husk doesn't have any form of run-length encoding

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing - it doesn't have it as a single builtin command, so ```g``` = group on equal adjacent values is the closest we can get...

Answer (score 1):

### Bash / GNU core utils (40)

```
fold -1|uniq -c|sort -k2 -k1r|uniq -f1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py0/J0VB17CmNC@zUEE3uaY4v6hEQTfbCIgNi6CiaYb//ycmJyUmJiUBCSBITgYA)

Output when input is "acbaabbbaaaaacc":

```
      5 a
      3 b
      2 c
```

Explanation:

- `fold -1` adds a newline after each character
- `uniq -c` counts the number of consecutive identical lines
- `sort -k2 -k1r` sorts the result so as the maximum count for each character comes first
- `uniq -f1` keeps only the first line for each character

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer.

Comment: Thank you @RedwolfPrograms :-)

Answer (score 0):

### Python 3, 88 bytes

```
from re import*;a=input();[(i[0],len(max(i))) for i in(findall(l+"+",a)for l in set(a))]
```

Outputs in a format of:

```
[('b', 3), ('c', 2), ('a', 5)]
```

Comment: This doesn't take input, but otherwise looks like a good approach.

Comment: Also you're missing an `import re` or `__import__('re')` for the findall.

Comment: fixed, I forgot I was testing it interactively ;)

Comment: Your byte count was different, I saw the discrepancy and fixed that part of the code.  I also changed to byte count, not char count.

Answer (score 0):

## Python3 - <del>111</del>, <del>126</del>, <del>115</del> <del>114</del> 111 bytes

Executable code that will read 1 line (only use lowercase letters a-z)

```
d={}.fromkeys(map(chr,range(97,123)),0)
for c in input():d[c]+=1
[print("%s=%d"%(p,d[p]))for p in d if d[p]>0]
```

Edit: Excluded unnecessary output on request from @Therare

The output looks nice

```
~/codegolf $ python3 maxseq.py 
helloworld
l=3
o=2
h=1
e=1
d=1
w=1
r=1
```

Comment: You really should exclude the unnecessary output. (I think)

Comment: "fixed" the output

Comment: You can remove spaces between braces, numbers and keywords, such as `for` or `if`.

Comment: I think you've misread the questions. `l=2` and `o=1` for "helloworld"

Comment: You're counting total appearances instead of maximum consecutive appearances.

Comment: I do not think I read the question at all! I'll update with a new solution later

Answer (score 0):

## Julia, 85

```
f(s)=(l=0;n=1;a=Dict();[c==l?n+=1:(n>get(a,l,1)&&(a[l]=n);n=1;l=c) for c in s*" "];a)
julia> f("acbaabbbaaaaacc")
{'a'=>5,'c'=>2,'b'=>3}
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript - <strike>141</strike> <strike>137</strike> 125

I don't like regex :)

```
function g(a){i=o=[],a=a.split('');for(s=1;i<a.length;){l=a[i++];if(b=l==a[i])s++;if(!b|!i){o[l]=o[l]>s?o[l]:s;s=1}}return o}
```

Run

```
console.log(g("acbaabbbaaaaacc"));
```

outputs

```
[ c: 2, a: 5, b: 3 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, <strike>109</strike> <strike>104</strike> <strike>100</strike> 98 bytes

```
function c(s){q=l={};s.split('').map(function(k){q[k]=Math.max(n=k==l?n+1:1,q[l=k]|0)});return q}
```

Example usage:

```
console.log(c("aaaaaddfffabbbbdb"))
```

outputs:

```
{ a: 5, d: 2, f: 3, b: 4 }
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <strike>104</strike> <strike>102</strike> 96

```php
<?php function _($s){while($n=$s[$i++]){$a[$n]=max($a[$n],$n!=$s[$i-2]?$v=1:++$v);}print_r($a);}
```

usage

```php
_('asdaaaadddscc');
```

printed

```php
Array ( [a] => 4 [s] => 1 [d] => 3 [c] => 2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Java 247**

```
import java.util.*;public class a{public static void main(String[]a){Map<Character, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();for(char c:a[0].toCharArray()){Integer v=m.get(c);m.put(c,v==null?1:v+1);}for(char c:m.keySet())System.out.println(c+"="+m.get(c));}}
```

Comment: Does `import java.util.*;` work in Java?

Comment: yes and i paste old code

Comment: The OP said it could just be a function/method so you can shorten this to simply the method.

Comment: This outputs all occurrences of the character in the String, not the longest substrings consisting of the character. For example, `acbaabbbaaaaacc` outputs `a=8; b=4; c=3` instead of `a=5; b=3; c=2`.

Answer (score 0):

### R (<strike>219</strike>, <strike>213</strike>, <strike>197</strike>, <strike>196</strike>, <strike>191</strike>, <strike>165</strike>, <strike>169</strike>, <strike>157</strike>, 163 characters)

The `data.table` version added. There was an error in the previous `data.table` version.

**Golfed `data.table` version (163)**

```
require(data.table);f=function(x){x=strsplit(x,"")[[1]];data.table(x=x,y=cumsum(c(1,x[-1]!=head(x,-1))))[,.N,list(x,y)][order(-N)][!duplicated(x),paste0(x,"=",N)]}
```

**Ungolfed `data.table` version**

```
require(data.table)
f <- function(x) {
  x <- strsplit(x, "")[[1]]
  data.table(a=x, y=cumsum(c(1, x[-1] != head(x, -1))))[
  , .N, list(a, y)][order(-N)][!duplicated(a), paste0(a, "=", N)]
}
```

---

**Golfed `data.frame` version (174)**

```
f=function(x){x=strsplit(x,"")[[1]];d=data.frame(a=x,y=cumsum(c(1,x[-1]!=head(x,-1))));d=aggregate(d$y,d,length);d=d[order(-d$x),];d=d[!duplicated(d$a),];paste0(d$a,"=",d$x)}
```

**Ungolfed `data.frame` version**

```
f <- function(x) {
  x <- strsplit(x, "")[[1]]
  d <- data.frame(a = x, y = cumsum(c(1, x[-1] != head(x, -1))))
  d <- aggregate(d$y, d, length)
  d <- d[order(-d$x), ]
  d <- d[!duplicated(d$a), ]
  paste0(d$a, "=", d$x)
}

f("acbaabbbaaaaacc")
f("acbaabbbaaaaaccdee")
```

Answer (score 0):

### C 169

Iterates each printable character in ASCII table and counts max from input string.

```
#define N 128
int c,i,n;
char Y[N],*p;
int main(){gets(Y);
for(c=33;c<127;c++){p=Y;n=0,i=0;while(*p){if(*p==c){i++;}else{n=(i>n)?i:n;i=0;}p++;}
if(n>0) printf("%c=%d\n",c,n);}
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this? It doesn't look like it produces correct output on a lot of strings , and also doesn't meet the spec which says that input can be up to 1024 long... plus, there's a lot of easy golfing techniques that you've missed. :)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript 116

```
prompt(x={}).replace(/(.)\1*/g,function(m,l){n=m.length
if(!x[l]||x[l]<n)x[l]=n})
for(k in x)console.log(k+'='+x[k])
```

Answer (score 0):

### Groovy - 80 chars

Based on [this clever answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32573/21004) by [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor) :

```
t=args[0];t.toSet().each{i=0;
while(t.contains(it*++i));
println "${it}=${i-1}"}
```

Output:

```
$ groovy Golf.groovy abbcccdddd
d=4
b=2
c=3
a=1
```

Ungolfed:

```
t=args[0]

t.toSet().each { c ->
    i=0
    s=c

    // repeat the char c with length i
    // e.g. "b", "bb", "bbb", etc
    // stop when we find a length that is not in t:
    // this is the max + 1
    while (t.contains(s)) {
        i++
        s=c*i
    }
    println "${c}=${i-1}"
}
```

Comment: Does that actually count the maximum sequence length? I don't see how that would work correctly for a string like "aabbbbaaaabbbbbba" although I don't know Groovy either.

Comment: It works for your example. I've updated the ungolfed version. Note that "a" * 4 == "aaaa" .

Comment: Ah, I see how it works now. Clever.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript (E6) 103

A javascript solution that cares about the requested output format.

```
F=a=>(p=q={},m={},[...a].map(x=>(x!=p&&(q[p=x]=0),m[x]>++q[x]?0:m[x]=q[x])),''+[i+'='+m[i]for(i in m)])
```

**Ungolfed**

```
F=a=>(
  p=q={}, m={},
  [...a].map(
    x=>(
      x!=p && (q[p=x]=0),
      m[x] > ++q[x] ? 0 : m[x] = q[x]
    )
  ),
  '' + [i+'='+m[i] for(i in m)]
)
```

**Test**

In Firefox console

```
console.log(F("aaaaaddfffabbbbdb"))
```

> a=5,d=2,f=3,b=4

Answer (score 0):

It's written in Python, in order to run the code, just call thefunction maxsequence(str). For instance, `maxsequence('aaaaaannndmdejlsfnsfsssssnnnnnxxx')` or
`maxsequence("kdkdkdkdjeeeiwwwnnnmdnnsbjdiiiiiiiiiidndbbcbbccbcvcvdddcjdjdjwwwwwwkkkkxlxllllllll")`

```python
def maxsequence(str):

    count = 1 # count if the letters are repeat
    step = 0 # once the next letter changed, step = count.
    countArray = [] # put all the sequence numbers in an array
    lettersArray = [] # put all the repeat letters in an array
    max = 0
    # for calculating the max of the array, it needs two indexes to do that
    indexFirst = 0
    indexNext = 1
    i = 0
    while(i<len(str) and i<=(len(str)-2)):
        if(str[i]==str[i+1]):
            count += 1
            step = count
        else:
            lettersArray.append(str[i])
            step = count
            countArray.append(step)
            count = 1
        i += 1
    countArray.append(step)
    lettersArray.append(str[i])

    while(countArray[indexFirst]>=countArray[indexNext] and indexNext<(len(countArray)-1)):
        indexNext += 1
        if(countArray[indexFirst]<=countArray[indexNext]):
            indexFirst = indexNext
    max = countArray[indexFirst]

    for i in range(len(lettersArray)):
        print lettersArray[i],"=",countArray[i]

    print "The max sequence is:", max
    return max
```

Comment: Note that the question is a [tag:code-golf], and that means that you should write the shortest code possible. You can do this by removing comments, removing whitespace and using one-letter variable names. After doing that, include the character count in your answer. Also, it is a good idea to provide a un-golfed version of your code. The code that you have now is a good example of a un-golfed code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I misunderstood the goal of this forum.

Answer (score 0):

## Scala – 99 as program, 97 as function

Program (reads one line from stdin)

```
for((k,v)<-"(.)\\1*".r.findAllIn(Console.in.readLine).toSeq.groupBy(_(0)))println(k+"="+v.max.size)
```

Function:

```
def f(s:String)=for((k,v)<-"(.)\\1*".r.findAllIn(s).toSeq.groupBy(_(0)))println(k+"="+v.max.size)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure - 105 bytes

I'm learning Clojure at the moment and what would be a better way to do it than golfing? So, here's my second entry to this challenge.

```clojure
(def f #(apply str(for[c(distinct %)](str c\=(apply max(map count(re-seq(re-pattern(str c\+))%)))"\n"))))
```

Examples:

```
=> (f "acbaabbbaaaaacc")
"a=5\nc=2\nb=3\n"
=> (f "aaaabaa")
"a=4\nb=1\n"
=> (println (f "acbaabbbaaaaacc"))
a=5
c=2
b=3
```

Answer (score 0):

### J 45

```
~.,.'=',.":@({.@>>.//.$&>)@(<;.2~2&(~:/\),1:)
```

As a verb. Though for using it , you'd need to assign it to a name, eg:

```
f=:~.,.'=',.":@({.@>>.//.$&>)@(<;.2~2&(~:/\),1:)
f 'acbaabbbaaaaacc'
a=5
c=2
b=3
```

Short explanation:

```
                                @(        2&(~:/\),1:): find where neighbors are different
                                   <;.2~              : cut in these places
            (              $&> )                      : get the length of the string in the box
             ({.@>)                                   : get the first letter from the box
                   (>./)/.                            : get the maximum for each unique char
~.,.'=',.":@(                  )                      : Output: letter = stringified value
```

Answer (score 0):

### [BACCHUS](https://sites.google.com/site/bacchuslanguage/), 41

```
'acbaabbbaaaaacc'j:A=·z#:B=($A,$0h:a(·>0.$0,'=',·+)?),$B¨n
```

I have discounted the actual parameter String.

Explanation

`j:A=` Transform the String in a block (some sort of array) and stores it in `A` variable.

`·z#:B=` Read last value on the stack (the block) and removes al duplicates, storing it in `B`.

`(` Open for each

`$A,$0h:a` counts how many times the current element of the for each is present in A (read as a String) and pushes this value to Stack (this avoid inmediate printing of the value).

`(` Open if

`·>0.` is last value is > 0 then

`$0,'=',·+` Concatenates current for each element, '=' and last value in stack (that will be printed out)

`)?` Close if

`,$B¨` Close for each indicating the block to loop over (`B`).

`n` Indicates that the output must be space separated

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 107 bytes

```
#(apply str(for[p(vals(group-by last(partition-by(fn[i]i)%)))](str(ffirst p)\=(apply max(map count p))\,)))
```

Returns `"a=5,c=2,b=3,"` for the example input. This would have been 89 bytes, returning `([\a 5] [\c 2] [\b 3])`:

```
#(for[p(vals(group-by last(partition-by(fn[i]i)%)))][(ffirst p)(apply max(map count p))])
```

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 41 bytes

```apl
{(⊃,'=',⍕∘≢)¨l[∪⍳⍨⊃¨l←n[⍒≢¨n←⍵⊂⍨1,2≠/⍵]]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RqjUddzTrqtuo6j3qnPuqY8ahzkeahFTnRjzpWPerd/Kh3BVAayAeqzIt@1DsJKH1oRR6Q96h366OuJqC8oY7Ro84F@kB@bGwt0Ez1xOSkxMSkJCABBMnJ6lxp6uWJOTk5qcXF6gA)

Ungolfed:

```apl
{
  n←⍵⊂⍨1,2≠/⍵
  l←n[⍒≢¨n]
  (⊃,'=',⍕∘≢)¨l[∪⍳⍨⊃¨l]
}
```

`{` anonymous function

`2≠/⍵` pair-wise sliding window inequality of the argument
 `1,` prepend a one
 `⍵⊂⍨` use that to partition the argument
 `n←` store in *n*

`n[`…`]` index *n* with:
  `⍒` the descending order of
  `≢¨` the length of each element in
  `⍵` argument
 `l←` store in *l*

`l[`…`]` index *l* with:
  `∪` the unique of
  `⍳⍨` the first occurrence of each element of
  `⊃¨l` the first element of each of *l*
 `(`…`)¨` apply the following tacit function on each element
  `⊃` the first element
  `,` concatenated to
  `'='` an equal sign
  `,` concatenated to
  `⍕∘≢` the formatted length

`}`

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 17 bytes

```
ÙvIγʒyå}€gZy…ÿ=ÿ,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@394Zpnnuc2nJlUeXlr7qGlNelTlo4Zlh/fbHt6v8/9/YnJSYmJSEpAAguRkAA)

```
ÙvIγʒyå}€gZy…ÿ=ÿ,   Argument s
Ùv                  For each c in s uniquified
  Iγ                Split s into chunks of consecutive equal elements
    ʒyå}            Filter: Keep elements that contain c
        €g          Map to element length
          Z         Get max
           y…ÿ=ÿ,   Print "c=max"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 192 bytes

```
import java.util.*;s->{int p=0,c=0;Map<Character,Integer>m=new HashMap();for(byte b:s.getBytes()){c=p==b?c+1:1;m.merge((char)(p=b),c,Math::max);}m.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println(k+"="+v));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU89T8MwEJ3pr7Ay2TS12jWpg0SFBEOnjojh4jqJ29ix7Eugqvrbw0HZeMN9vad3dyeYYHU6nmfrwhCRnaiXI9pePpaLf7Nm9Brt4H/IMNa91Uz3kBLbg/XsumCEv3lCQErTYI/MEcsPGK1v3z8YxDYJEj/sBp9GZ@L2TlWsUXNaVVfrkQW1zrVal3sI210HETSamL95NK2JlVPefLJXSB3xXJTNEHl9QcPqIsnW4DPViQtx1SooVT/p5abYlE7SstZwrslQ8KBqket8D9gVhYMvUd6cJKcX0B3n53wSq@pwSWicHEaUgW7E3vPzMlPZchIkn8vfjwmNBK1NQJ6BrgHqmgJB60zcNbfFbf4G)

### Java, 251 bytes (with regular expressions)

```
import java.util.regex.*;import java.util.function.*;s->{Matcher m=Pattern.compile("(.)\\1*").matcher(s);Map<String,Integer>a=new HashMap();while(m.find())a.merge(m.group(1),m.group().length(),Math::max);a.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println(k+'='+v));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZA/b8IwEMXn8imsLPggWGIlJEtVqR2QKjGWDhfjJIbYjuxLoEJ89tQUOvEG/3m/d76TDzjg4rA/jtp0zhM7xLvoSbdilk2ePK9qdY7kCVS9laSdvVV1fdlqyWSLIbANassuExb18AMhxW1wes9MpHxLXtv665uhrwPE8Murs6E3yq/vqGBVPoZFcdkgyUZ5ZvJPJFLeCulMp1vFEy5gt1vOEhDmHuIBsg12jyfSD0txdl9gbtWJvWNoIuSQnZpbuRGVtnsOgCK2rW9G7V3f8SWk/0cQrbI1NRzSOEezWhk8Q4aicv4NZcP5MR1gUWx/AikjXE@ii52ptfw4n@bT@QCQXcfs7yuiKoFSqo54grJELMu4REmZwD1znVzHXw)

Answer (score -1):

Java Code:
Out of interest I just found a solution will further enhance soon.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
```

import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MaxSequenceLength {
    private HashMap characterCount = new HashMap<>();

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    new MaxSequenceLength().validateInput(inputScanner.nextLine());
    inputScanner.close();
}

private void validateInput(String inputString) {
    if (inputString.length() <= 1024) {
        scanInput(inputString.toCharArray());
    }
}

private void scanInput(char[] characterArrayInput) {
    for (char tempCharacter : characterArrayInput) {
        if ((int) tempCharacter < 65
                || ((int) tempCharacter > 90 && (int) tempCharacter < 97)
                || (int) tempCharacter > 122) {
            continue;
        } else if (characterCount.containsKey(tempCharacter)) {
            characterCount.put(tempCharacter,
                    characterCount.get(tempCharacter) + 1);
        } else {
            characterCount.put(tempCharacter, 1);
        }
    }
    for (Entry<Character, Integer> tempEntry : characterCount.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(tempEntry.getKey() + " = "
                + tempEntry.getValue());
    }
}
```

}

The code would ignore all the other symbols and give only case sensitive character output.

Comment: This is a code-golf question, which means you should try to use the least number of characters to solve the problem.

Answer (score -2):

### Python (<del>62</del> 55)

```
n=raw_input()
print map(lambda x:[x,n.count(x)],set(n))
```

Old answer:

```
n=raw_input()
s=set(n)
print zip(s,map(lambda x:[x,n.count(x)],s))
```

Comment: You should output the maximum sequence length foe each character, not the count of each character. `aaaabaa` -> `a=4 b=1`

Comment: oh, well I'll leave this here as an example of how not to read a question!

Comment: You can edit your answer with a correct answer, if you wish. Otherwise I would recommend either making it a Community Wiki or deleting it, so you won't lose reputation from the most likely incoming downvotes.

Comment: The map/lambda idiom `map(lambda x:expression_in(x),list)` is longer that the equivalent comprehension `[expression_in(x)for x in list]`.

Comment: Oh cool thanks, but that returns a generator object, so to output it all you'd have to do: `n=raw_input() for i in ((x,n.count(x))for x in set(n)):print i` which is longer, unless I've missed something

Comment: I was thinking `print[(x,n.count(x))for x in set(n))]` or (for Python 3) `[print(x,n.count(x))for x in set(n))]`.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks! That is clever