# Convert 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9 to "one", "two", "three", etc

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

## Winner: [professorfish's bash answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32151/convert-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-and-9-to-one-two-three-etc/32232#32232)! An entire 9 bytes! Wow!

You may continue to submit your answer, however you can no longer win. Original post kept for posterity:

---

Your goal is to convert a **whole** number between 1-9 into the word it represents.

- You will not need to worry about decimals
- The user will input a number. Assume that they will never enter anything 10 or higher
- The user must type the number at some point, **however** the method the program reads it does not matter. It can be with stdin, reading a text file, etc, however the user must press the 9 button on their keyboard (for example) at some point
- It is not case sensitive (ie, "one", "One", "oNe", "OnE", etc are all acceptable)
- HTTP/etc requests are allowed, **however** any code executed by the server the request is made to counts towards the byte count of your final code (e.g. if I had a C++ program make a HTTP request, the PHP code used in the HTTP request counts)
- Anything that can compile and run is acceptable

---

- This contest **has ended** on June 27th, 2014 (7 days from posting).
- This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins

Comment: Is trailing whitespace (i.e. `one  `) acceptable?

Comment: @grc Yes, as long as the program outputs the word.

Comment: The user must type the number at some point. It can be with stdin, reading a text file, etc, however the user must press the `9` button on their keyboard (for example) at some point.

Comment: In languages like Julia, you can input variables at the prompt like this: `n=5` - can we use this as our input method, and count the `n=` part as 2 characters in our code, and then use `n` in the rest of the code?

Comment: You can do whatever you want as long as the user inputs the character `5` at some point (have them enter it, append it yourself, etc)

Comment: you should specify that only the given number may be printed and not the other numbers.

Comment: @Pinna_be for example, if I input `3`, you can't output `one two three four five six seven eight nine` even though you *technically* output `three`. Similarly, you can't output `three seven`, etc.

Comment: So we can use multiple files and the final byte count is just the sum of the files' byte counts?

Comment: Do spoken words count?

Comment: Can the output be as a file?

Comment: This question was quite nice. But I don't like the adding of the date limit. Especially, the date limit has been added just before the date limit, not 7 days before.

Comment: If http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32151/convert-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-and-9-to-one-two-three-etc/32493#32493 answer is accepted, why isn't mine which is exactly the same, only shorter? http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32298/15168

Comment: Because you edited your answer to make it valid after the deadline. As of the deadline you had an invalid submission.

Comment: @CousinCocaine — Spoken words are words. ;-) In fact, spoken words existed long before written words.

Comment: Chipperyman, Except that the answer you declared winner ex æquo is invalid too, for the same reason as you rejected the answer by @CousinCocaine.

Comment: I never said spoken words aren't words, however as of the contest ending, it only worked if the input was 4. And Nicolas, can you link me to the rejected answer? I might have just not noticed it if it is <= 9 chars.

Comment: Chipperyman has declared [the answer by Registered User](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32493/12943) winner ex æquo. But this answer misses taking the input. The other solutions — including mines — would be shorter too if they placed the “input” directly at the target spot. Besides, Chipperyman has rejected [the answer by CousinCocaine](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32298/12943) because it missed taking the input. In addition, the answer by Registered User is a replica of CousinCocaine's answer. This is unfair — to say the least.

Comment: Oh, he told me that it worked for any number and I didn't know the language so I figured I was missing something. I guess he didn't win.

Comment: What is labelled “original post” here is not [the original post](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/32151/1).

Comment: I feel like you're just trying to argue with me at this point. I (in my opinion) obviously meant the post before the winner was announced. Does it really matter that it's not the **true** original post?

Comment: "Original post kept for prosperity": I think you meant _posterity_ (future generations), not _prosperity_ (getting rich).

Comment: The "winning" answer violates a standard loophole - no relying on external sources. `bsdgames` is not included with bash most of the time.

Comment: I wonder which human language has number names that are most compressible.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Bash (with bsdgames), 9

```bsh
number -l
```

Reads from standard input.

I don't know why there's a utility for this, but whatever.

Comment: I'm not sure I like installing bsdgames and then calling it "bash", though I'll admit that my reservation is subjective.

Comment: @PaulDraper Neither do I. I didn't post this as a serious answer, I think one of the other answers deserved to be accepted

Comment: Ain't this a standard loophole?

Comment: @Quincunx yes, it basically is. Although most things are external utilities in Bash, I wouldn't count the bsdgames package as something very permissible (unlike grep, wget, coreutils, sed, bc...).

Answer (score 132):

### Python 2, 64

```py
print' ottffssennwhoiieiieoruvxvgn  ere ehe  e   nt'[input()::9]
```

This is what the string looks like with some extra whitespace (try reading vertically):

```
o t t f f s s e n
n w h o i i e i i
e o r u v x v g n
    e r e   e h e 
    e       n t
```

As explained in the comments below, `[input()::9]` starts at the given index and selects every ninth subsequent character.

Comment: Oh, shit, I like this. Probably worth pointing out that this is python 2, by the way.

Comment: Explain please! :)

Comment: @ChristoferOlsson `input()::9` is a range from `input()` to the end of the string in steps of `9`, like `1,10,19,28,37` or `3,12,21,30,39`, which are exactly the indices at which the letters for the corresponding word are found.

Comment: @m.buettner thanks! That's nice.

Comment: Python 3 would _only_ be 7 characters longer right? The brackets for print() and adding int() around the input(). Also would be safer than using Python 2's input.

Comment: @JeromeJ yes, that's correct.

Comment: Isn't this something like what a rail-fence cipher does? (+1 for a neat solution by the way.)

Comment: Visual, clever. I like this one !

Answer (score 18):

## Common Lisp - 22 bytes

Here's a general one (not just for one-ten):

```
(format nil"~R"(read))
```

Oh, you want ordinals (first, second, ... three-hundredth...)? Ok!

```
(format nil"~:R"(read))
```

Comment: Isn't this a standard loophole?

Comment: Loophole in what sense? It's clearly defined in Hyperspec: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/22_cba.htm

Comment: As in this: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1078/20356

Comment: Whether it's a standard loophole or not, it's what I came here to post, too.  +1 :)

Comment: @TheRare I'll remember for the next time. Although I don't quite agree with it.

Comment: @TheRare Looking at the comments to that answer, I don't think there is strong community consensus that this is a loophole.  My feeling is that questions need to explicitly ban use of this kind of built in function if they are not to be used.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma That is the reason I asked if it's one. Might be that my meaning got a little warped.

Comment: This seems more like an answer in SO than in PCG to me...

Answer (score 16):

## BASH 51

So I made another one using my second idea plus some help from others:

```
set one two three four five six seven eight nine

$X
```

Where 'X' is the number you want.

---

## BASH 48 (67)

**67 with `\n` line breaks**

I'm not sure if this totally counts, because it's reading from a file, but:

`sed -n Xp a`

Where "X" is the input and where `a` is a file with:

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
```

The file is 36 chars, and the bash command is 13.

How it works:

> Each line in the file is numbered, starting with 1. So 'one' is on the 1st line, 'two' on the 2nd. The command, `sed -n 'Xp' a` says, "Please print what's listed on line 'X' of file 'a'" `sed` is a Unix stream editor. `-n` means be silent, or only essentially ignore everything else. `Xp` means print what's on line 'X'.

Comment: @Quincunx updated my post from 46 -> 49

Comment: @Quincunx I added a spoiler. Hopefully I explained it well.

Comment: Nice first answer! Thank you for taking the time to figure out how we format our answers on this site. Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf!

Comment: For the record, this does fit within the rules because you could reasonably assume the text file had a number input by the user.

Comment: You didn't count the linefeeds in `a`.

Comment: One byte less than before, accepts a command-line argument and doesn't require additional files: http://pastebin.com/qdbXKQGP Bash will complain about the missing heredoc delimiter, but it will run fine with Dash and Zsh.

Comment: @Dennis oh cool I like it. Am I supposed to edit my answer with yours now? Sorry, am new to code golf.

Comment: That depends entirely on you.

Comment: You can omit the `'` quotes.  You could also try using a here string instead of the external file.  But you really should count the line breaks in your file.

Comment: You might be able to use the `d` command within `sed` instead of `-n`

Comment: @Dennis I'll add yours in when I get back to my laptop. I'm on my phone at the moment and it's hard to edit.

Comment: It certainly is. By the way, your new approach is very similar to [professorfish's](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32196). Yours has a syntax error; Bash uses `()` for array declaration, not `[]`.

Comment: @Dennis you're right. I fixed it. Stupid error because I wrote too much JS.

Comment: You're also missing the `echo`.

Comment: @Dennis technically it prints the correct number, plus a bunch of other junk. If you only wanted the number you'd use echo, yes.

Comment: So that was by design. Sneaky! It's customary to count *functional* whitespace, so one linefeed between the first and the second command has to be counted. That gives a total of 58 bytes. I'd also change `X` to `$1` to comply with the question's input requirements.

Comment: I'm not sure I under stand the "change x" part @Dennis

Comment: I won't pretend that I fully understand the input requirements of this question, but the usual forms of accepting user input with Bash scripts/functions are reading from STDIN and command line arguments. `$1` refers to the first argument or the script/function, so it's the cheaper choice.

Comment: `set one two ... nine` then user input is `${!X}`  to save 4 bytes

Comment: @Dennis Oh, okay. I see what you mean. I updated it using `set` and `$X`

Comment: Oh, and I should mention thanks for the warm welcome, @Quincunx Also, are line breaks 1 or two bytes?

Comment: They count as one byte.

Comment: 59 bytes: `sed -n $1p<<<'one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\nfive\nsix\nseven\neight\nnine'` (replace `\n`s with line breaks). Takes a number as command line argument.

Comment: The first solution, with `$1`, misses the input.

Comment: What shell are you using @Nicolas Barbulesco ?

Comment: @eric_lagergren — I tested this with `bash` on Mac OS X. This does not work. I did test your code, `$X`. The answer has to take the digit as input. I don't have to edit the script to place the digit inside the code.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco the question doesn't ask for the input to be inside the code. It just says `The user must type the number at some point, however the method the program reads it does not matter. It can be with stdin, reading a text file, etc, however the user must press the 9 button on their keyboard (for example) at some point`

Answer (score 16):

#### C# - 127 ( 86 / 46)

If you only take the executable part...

```c#
Console.Write(((HourOfDay)Console.Read()-48));
```

and if `HourOfDay` would have been part of the the System namespace you would need 46 chars. Unfortunately it sits in `System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory` which makes it 86...the other noise spoils it.

This is compileable and runnable from the commandline (127 chars):

```c#
using System;class P{static void Main(){Console.Write((System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.HourOfDay)Console.Read()-48);}}
```

if saved to a file called cg2.cs

```
csc cg2.cs /r:System.DirectoryServices.dll  && cg2
```

**How does this work?**

[`HourOfDay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.hourofday(v=vs.110).aspx)  is an enum type so we can use names instead of magic constants. Enum types have a ToString() implementation that gives you the [name of the value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname(v=vs.110).aspx). You can cast an int to an enum. [Console.Read()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx) reads a character from the input stream represented as an integer. typing '1' gives [49](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout), substract 48 to get 1, cast/box to `HourOfDay` to return 'One'.

[Take a look at the Powershell version of this same trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32181/9393)

Comment: How does this work ? Let's say I enter 9. What does the program do then ?

Comment: [I love how Micro$oft presents things ! The order of the entries is completely absurd.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.hourofday(v=vs.110).aspx) ^^

Comment: What does this `-48` do here ?

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco added an *How does this work?* paragraph. Does it make sense?

Comment: Rene, thank you, it is clearer now. The `-48` is there to convert character code to integer.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco - It's sorted alphabetically.  Which makes sense in every context except "These words are numbers".  Since I'm sure the documentation is automatically generated, it wouldn't make sense to special case the one article.

Comment: In reality, the cast to `HourOfDay` occurs *before* the subtraction (cast operator has higher precedence than `-`), but to my surprise C# still allows that.

Comment: @Timwi Hmmm, The IL doesn't show a cast OpCode but only a box OpCode just before the call to write to get an object?!

Comment: @Bobson — The alphabetical order is non-sense. *The days in the week are friday, monday, saturday, sunday, thursday, tuesday, wednesday.* :-)

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco - [Yep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx).  Do note, though, that the order they are listed in is not the order of their `int` values.  `"The value of the constants in this enumeration ranges from DayOfWeek.Sunday to DayOfWeek.Saturday. If cast to an integer, its value ranges from zero (which indicates DayOfWeek.Sunday) to six (which indicates DayOfWeek.Saturday)."`

Answer (score 14):

## Befunge 98, <s>116</s> <s>105</s> 103 bytes

```
&1-       v
vvvvvvvvvj<
"""""""""
etnxereoe
nheivuewn
igvsiorto
nie"ffh""
"es ""t
 ""   "
>>>>>>>>>4k,@
```

Befunge was not made for this...

Explanation:

```
&1-           ;Grab the input number (`n`) and subtract 1 from it
&1-       v   ;Start moving downwards
          <   ;Start moving leftwards
         j    ;Jump `n - 1` characters to the left.
vvvvvvvvvj    ;Redirect each of the possible locations to jump to, sending the IP down.

        "     ;If `n` was 1, push `o, n, e` onto the stack (`o` is at the bottom)
        e
        n
        o
        "

       "      ;If `n` was 2, push `t, w, o` onto the stack
       o
       w
       t
       "

    *
    *
    *

"             ;If `n` was 9, push `n, i, n, e` onto the stack
e
n
i
n
"

>>>>>>>>>     ;Collect all the different possible positions the IP could be in, and send it right
>>>>>>>>>4k,  ;Print the top 5 chars. If there are less than 5, the rest are null characters. This is allowed
            @ ;End of program
```

Comment: @Dennis I can't see how that could be so hard. Simply take the file, turn it into a `char[][]`, keep an `x` and `y` location, and execute the character at that location. The hardest thing would be defining the operation for every possible character.

Comment: You can easily save two bytes with a `&1-`.

Answer (score 11):

## Javascript 68

Atob / btoa can be a poor's man compressing tool
 <s>(but if you want to try this in console, you cannot copy from the formatted text you see at once. Go to 'edit' and copy from the source panel)</s>

Markdown editor does not like some of the characters in this answer: some characters get lost at saving. Still, I think it's an editor problem, not mine. The lost characters are perfectly valid 8 bit unicode chars.
(Or else I'm wrong, if this issue was already debated in meta, let me know)
Here is the version with offending characters escaped, each sequence \xNN should count 1

```
alert(btoa("×C§{Dð£Dá­ç´\x16\x8b«ÐX¯{D¢ÇD\x9e½éô\x12(!·Cb\x9dí").split(0)[prompt()])
```

**Simple Test**

In firefox console:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
.map(x=>x +',' btoa("×C§{Dð£Dá­ç´\x16\x8b«ÐX¯{D¢ÇD\x9e½éô\x12(!·Cb\x9dí").split(0)[x])
```

Comment: I tried something similar but couldn't figure out a valid base64 string starting with a number. I think you answer has been corrupted by stackexchange though.

Comment: @nderscore, damn your'right. Amending the post, still it's valid according to me

Comment: With the version that has the escaped characters, everything works but 3 and 8, the output `Tree` and `EightF`.

Comment: @Quincunx 'Tree' is me not speak english

Answer (score 9):

## Javascript 73

```javascript
alert('0one0two0three0four0five0six0seven0eight0nine'.split(0)[prompt()])
```

## 69

```javascript
alert(btoa("ôéÞõ5õ1ëxO_¢êý|ÞöÈ±õ'xß^hSôØ§{Ý").split(9)[prompt()])
```

Comment: Technically wouldn't `alert('0one0two0three0four0five0six0seven0eight0nine'.split(0)[#])` be the same thing but save you 8 bytes? The user still inputs the number they want...

Comment: @eric_lagergren do you mean the user would have to change the number in the source? I don't think that would count as input.

Comment: Oh, okay, I see what you mean. I suppose if you ran it like a command in the console it'd be part of the input as opposed to the source.

Answer (score 8):

## Perl, 55

```perl
$_=(nine,eight,seven,six,five,four,three,two,one)[-$_]
```

It is run with option `-p` (+1 byte), e.g.:

```bash
perl -pe '$_=(nine,eight,seven,six,five,four,three,two,one)[-$_]'
```

Input is expected in STDIN and output is written to STDOUT.

The code just generates an array and selects the right element. Option `-p` takes care of reading the input line into `$_` and prints the result in `$_`.

**Variations:**

- With trailing new line (+3):

  ```perl
  $_=(nine,eight,seven,six,five,four,three,two,one)[-$_].$/
  ```

  or (same byte count):

  ```perl
  s/./(nine,eight,seven,six,five,four,three,two,one)[-$&]/e
  ```

**Update:**

- Using bare words instead of `qw[...]` (thanks Zaid).
- Negative index saves a byte (thanks aragaer).

Comment: Save a couple of characters: `$_=(one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine)[$_-1]`

Comment: @Zaid: Thanks, it saved two bytes. (I am to used to `use strict`).

Comment: I don't like that "-1". `$_=(nine,eight,seven,six,five,four,three,two,one)[-$_]` - one character shorter.

Comment: @aragaer: Thanks, nice idea.

Answer (score 7):

### Oracle SQL - 46

```
select to_char(to_date(&1,'j'),'jsp')from dual
```

[Demonstration](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/31776)

This does include a [standard loophole](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1078/3419), I admit, but the SQL is shorter than Golfscript; I couldn't resist!

It works by (ab)using Oracle's [datetime format models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#i34924). `TO_DATE(n, 'j')` converts a number into a [Julian day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day), the number of days since January 1, 4712 BC. `TO_CHAR(<date>, 'jsp')` converts this back into the integer (though as a string). The `sp`, is a [format element suffix](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF51083) that spells the number. This'll actually work with quite a lot of numbers.

The `&1` is a substitution variable that'll only work with clients that accept it, for instance SQL*Plus.

Comment: I have a love/hate relationship with Oracle's RDBMS but this is nice.

Answer (score 6):

## CJam, <s>45</s> 43 bytes

```
"^AM-^L8M-xM-^L^US^_M-^WrM-rM- 1M-s^CHM-|M-X^HE,M-qM-^EM-q4"256bKb'ef+'j/li=
```

The above uses ^ and M- notation, since some characters are unprintable.

At the cost of 9 more bytes, unprintable characters can be avoided:

```
" one two three four five six seven eight nine"S/li=
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

#### How it works

```
" Convert the string into an integer by considering it a base-256 number.                ";

"^AM-^L8M-xM-^L^US^_M-^WrM-rM- 1M-s^CHM-|M-X^HE,M-qM-^EM-q4"256b

" Convert the integer from above into an array by considering it a base-20 number.       ";

Kb

" Add the ASCII character code of “e” to all elements of that array. This casts to char. ";

'ef+

" So far, we've pushed the string “jonejtwojthreejfourjfivejsixjsevenjeightjnine”.       ";

" Split the the above string where the character “j” occurs.                             ";

'j/

" Read an integer from STDIN and push the corresponding substring.                       ";

li=
```

#### Example

```
$ base64 -d > convert.cjam <<< IgGMOPiMFVMfl3LyoDHzA0j82AhFLPGF8TQiMjU2YktiJ2VmKydqL2xpPQ==
$ wc -c convert.cjam
43 convert.cjam
LANG=en_US cjam convert.cjam <<< 5
five
```

Comment: Wow, our answers are identical, even in length (I assume the user inputs a string).

Comment: @Quincunx: Alike minds think great! :P But reading user input will cost two bytes in CJam, so I'll have to think of something else...

Comment: @Quincunx: It should work with GolfScript as well, although it probably won't save bytes. Base64 dump: `IgGMOPiMFVMfl3LyoDHzA0j82AhFLPGF8TQiMjU2YmFzZSAyMGJhc2V7MTAxK30lIiIr`

Comment: This is what I managed to come up with; it's longer: http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=Oyc5Jwp%2BIgEELDBETApwEBAWBDdoR3tjN3FyVBp6QgQRH10iW3t9L10xMjhiYXNlW3suMjAlMTAxK1wyMC8ufWRvO10nZScrJ2onLz0%3D

Comment: Do you know what encoding golfscript expects for non-ascii characters? It seems to not be utf-8

Comment: @Quincunx: The official interpreter depends on `$LANG`. I don't know that the online interpreter does.

Comment: Okay. I give up. I managed to write something, but it doesn't work. At least I learned how to do file-io in python, though.

Comment: I haven't checked, but I don't think the `:c` is necessary, since int + char should give char.

Answer (score 5):

## GolfScript, 51 bytes

```ruby
~'
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine'n/=
```

It's a simple lookup table. The input is evaluated (`~`), an array of the values is created, and the index is found.

[Try it here](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OycxJwp%2BJwpvbmUKdHdvCnRocmVlCmZvdXIKZml2ZQpzaXgKc2V2ZW4KZWlnaHQKbmluZSduLz0%3D)

Comment: The user must input a string, you can't have it hard-coded. Also, your `Try it here` link has different code than the pasted code.

Comment: @Chipperyman The user does input a string in this program. The `Try it here` link's difference in code is because the webpage does not support user input. Change the string after the `;`, this is identical to user input.

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't know golfscript very well, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @Chipperyman: GolfScript places the contents of STDIN on the stack before executing the script itself.

Comment: Hah! I can beat you [by one byte](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32507)! ;-)

Answer (score 5):

## bash say (OS X): <s>3</s> 8

"Your goal is to convert a whole number between 1-9 into the word it represents"

Last time I checked, spoken words are words as well.
Previous attempt (accepts no input)

<s>`say 4`</s>

Edit, must be able to read input:

```
say|read
```

Type any number and the word comes out. I know the end date is due, but in my opinion I should have won the contest.

Example audio file: [four.aiff](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dut3a1d36jyt97w/four.aiff)

Comment: shouldn't be 5?

Comment: @rpax I don't believe the input is counted as a character, is it?

Comment: Thinking again...no. +1

Comment: This is clever. But this misses the input.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a valid answer because: It never accepts input from the user AND it only works if the number is 4.

Comment: CousinCocaine, you should *say* something how to run this answer : in the Terminal.

Comment: The comment by Chipperyman on this answer by CousinCocaine is true. But it is true for [the answer by @RegisteredUser](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32493/12943) too. However, Chipperyman has rejected this answer by CousinCocaine, and has declared the answer by Registered User winner ex æquo. In addition, the answer by Registered User is a replica of this answer by CousinCocaine. This is more than unfair.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2.x - <del>65</del> 64

Not as good as @grc 's answer, but certainly more legible :-)

```
'one two three four five six seven eight nine'.split()[input()-1]
```

One less char, thanks to @flornquake

```
'nine eight seven six five four three two one'.split()[-input()]
```

Comment: This one is nice too. :-) It works.

Comment: You can save one character like this: `'nine eight seven six five four three two one'.split()[-input()]`

Comment: Thats a Nice one !

Answer (score 4):

## Perl, 60 bytes

```
$_=(ZOneTwoThreeFourFiveSixSevenEightNine=~/.[a-z]*/g)[$_]
```

Requires the `-p` switch (two bytes).

#### Example

```
$ perl -p convert.pl <<< 5
Five
```

#### How it works

- `-p` reads from STDIN and saves the result in `$_`.
- `=~/.[a-z]*/g` splits the preceding bareword into substrings of one (uppercase) letter followed by any number of lowercase letters.
- `(…)` collects the substrings into an array.
- `[$_]` retrieves the substring corresponding to the user input.
- `$_=…` saves the result in `$_`.
- `-p` prints the value of `$_`.

Comment: I like the regex trick. +1

Answer (score 4):

## Bash + coreutils, 64

## Non-competitive compression concept

```
xxd -p<<<TàPnàõ:àsÀ~®@ãCN|tr 0-9a-d \\ng-inor-x|sed -n $1p
```

Some of the exotic characters here may not render well, so this script may be reconstructed from its base64 representation:

```
base64 -d <<< eHhkIC1wPDw8VOCLUIJu4PWWDzrgc8B+rkDjEoBDTnx0ciAwLTlhLWQgXFxuZy1pbm9yLXh8c2VkIC1uICQxcA==
```

#### Example output

```
$ ./n.sh 1
one
$ ./n.sh 9
nine
$
```

#### Explanation

It occurred to me that the string `one two three four five six seven eight nine` contains only the letters `efghinorstuvwx` and a space separator - 15 character values in total.  Thus each character can potentially be represented in 4 bits, or 2 characters per 1 byte.  We can use the hex representation of a byte as an easy way to split each byte into two hex digits. We can then transform the hex digits back to the letters we require using `tr` or similar.  As luck would have it, `rstuvwx` are consecutive, so may be expressed as `r-x` to `tr`.  The encoding is arranged such that `e` and `f` are left as-is, and that the words are line-break separated, so we can use `sed` to ouptut just the line we need.

This decoding process ends up using a fair amount of extra space, so makes this answer non-competitive as a shell-script-style answer, but may be a useful concept in other languages.

Answer (score 3):

### DOS Batch - 162 Chars (incl' line breaks)

This answer was inspired by @grc's Python answer, although I did have something similar in mind.

```
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@set s="ottffssennwhoiieiieoruvxvgn  ere ehe  e   nt
@set /a c=%1
@set z=!s:~%c%,1!
@if _%z%==_ exit /b
@echo %z%
@%0 %c%+9
```

Usage:

[Filename] [number]

For example, if the code is in a file called speak.bat, and you want to see the number "five", you would run it as:

`speak 5`

Also, the output is top-to-bottom, not left-to-right! So instead of

> five

you will see

> f
>   i
>   v
>   e

Answer (score 3):

## (pure) Bash, 64

Takes input as its first argument, assuming valid input.

```bsh
v=(o one two three four five six seven eight nine)
echo ${v[$1]}
```

Creates an array `v`, then accesses the element specified on the input. Since arrays are zero-indexed, I had to add a 0th element as a placeholder. Alternatively (thnx @DennisWilliamson for pointing this out):

```bsh
v=(one two three four five six seven eight nine)
echo ${v[$1-1]}
```

Comment: Same character count: `v=(one two three four five six seven eight nine)` and `echo ${v[$1-1]}`

Answer (score 3):

## Perl 36 (58 standalone)

```
use Number::Spell;say spell_number<>
```

Or, without additional modules:

```
say qw(one two three four five six seven eight nine)[<>-1]
```

Comment: Your first script does not work, on my Mac. `Can't locate Number/Spell.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.16 /Network/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.16 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.16.2 /System/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.16 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16 .) at toto.pl line 1.` `BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at toto.pl line 1.`

Comment: Your second script does not work, on my Mac. `syntax error at titi.pl line 1, near "say qw(one two three four five six seven eight nine)"` `Execution of titi.pl aborted due to compilation errors.`

Answer (score 3):

### Java 7 - 185

```
class Num{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("ONE,TWO,THREE,FOUR,FIVE,SIX,SEVEN,EIGHT,NINE".split(",")[(new java.util.Scanner(System.in)).nextInt()-1]);
    }}
```

Answer (score 3):

## C 111

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){printf("%.5s","one  two  threefour five six  seveneightnine"+5*(getchar()-'1'));}
```

The length here is carefully engineered so I can interpret it as binary and convert *that* to decimal. At only 7 characters, I'm confident I have a winner!

Comment: +1  [Code-golfers generally don't mind if your c code compiles with warnings](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2204/11259), as long as it meets the specs.  So you can omit the `#include` and `main()`'s return type.  Also a bit of refactoring of your expression: `main(){printf("%.5s","one  two  threefour five six  seveneightnine"+5*getchar()-245);}`.  86 chars by my count.

Comment: I don't get the length stuff, and I don't see where there would be 7 chars.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco: It's 111 characters--but if we treat the `111` as binary, that would convert to `7` in decimal.

Comment: Jerry, there is code golf running in your head !

Answer (score 2):

### VBScript <strike>98</strike> <strike>80</strike> 75

```
msgbox split(" one two three four five six seven eight nine")(inputbox(""))
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>93</s> <s>73</s> 68 bytes

```
<?=explode(' ','one two three four five six seven eight nine')[1-1];
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgEATAr2x3mmhBrcaHGDsXITEcAUR@jzPRxd7XfWOLj14cBDKJBqJ8iuISCatvgvWVyL4hszKA/nYFwQfKeJjZnEvvPw)

Comment: This is short-circuiting the input method. The other solutions — including mine, to come — would be shorter too if they placed the “input” directly at the target spot.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby 64

```
p %w?one two three four five six seven eight nine?[$*[0].to_i-1]
```

Comment: You can chop few more bytes by substituting 9 directly at the place of x

Comment: I don't see where this code takes in input.  And why write `9-1` when you can just say `8`?  Of course both `9-1` and `8` are wrong; this script outputs "nine" all the time and ignores input.

Answer (score 2):

## J - <s>68 or 60</s> 57 or 53 bytes

Interactive version (stdin):

```
>one`two`three`four`five`six`seven`eight`nine{~<:".1!:1]1
```

Function version:

```
f=:one`two`three`four`five`six`seven`eight`nine>@{~<:
```

Explanation:

```
f=:one`two`three`four`five`six`seven`eight`nine>@{~<:
                                                   <: Decrease by one
                                                 {~   Get the correct string
                                               >@     Unbox
```

`".(1!:1)1` reads a string and converts it to integer

Comment: You can save one char by writing it as a train (`(;:'one two blah')>@{~<:`) and another six by using the gerund ``one`two`blah`` instead of `;:`.

Comment: @algorithmshark Thanks! I'm still learning J. Although, wouldn't the train version require the text to be infinite rank (edit: apparently not... why not?) and the gerund version extra quotes (edit: oh, it creates a list of boxes)?

Comment: A fork can have a noun in the left argument, which is shorthand for a constant verb producing that noun with infinite rank (q.v. [the Dictionary](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dictf.htm)). And no, no extra quotes on the gerund: undefined names are treated as references to verbs, and the gerund for that is just a boxed string containing the name.

Comment: Also, you don't have to write the STDIN version as a verb expression: ``>one`two`three`four`five`six`seven`eight`nine{~<:".1!:1]1`` is 3 chars shorter.

Comment: @algorithmshark Haha, why didn't I do it that way?

Comment: @algorithmshark Also, your website is correct.

Answer (score 2):

### Powershell - <strike>91</strike> 74

```
[Enum]::ToObject([System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.HourOfDay],[Console]::Read()-48)
```

Found out how to cast to remove the Enum and ToObject call:

```
[System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.HourOfDay]([Console]::Read()-48)
```

**How does this work?**

HourOfDay is an enum type so we can use names instead of magic constants. Enum types have a ToString() implementation that gives you the name of the constant value. You can cast an int to an enum. [Console.Read()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx) reads a character from the input stream represented as an integer. typing '1' gives 49, substract 48 to get 1, cast to HourOfDay to return 'One'.

Because powershell does a ToString on all objects being written to the output stream and doesn't need the fluff to turn this into an executable this all that is needed besides powershell...

Answer (score 2):

**In AppleScript ; 123 chars.**

```
{"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"}'s item((display dialog""default answer"")'s text returned)
```

This script takes the input in a dialog. Then it gives the output in AppleScript’s *result*.

*Example :*

- Input : `6`
- Output : `"six"`

Here is a nicer version :

```
set l to {"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"}
set n to text returned of (display dialog "?" default answer "")
display dialog (l's item n) buttons ("OK") default button 1
```

This version displays the output in a nice dialog.

*Example :*

- Input : `9`
- Output : `nine`

*[ Answer edited ; slightly improved the dialog for the input ; still 124 chars. Answer edited again ; now 1 char less ! ]*

Comment: `set n to text returned of` ... Wow.

Answer (score 2):

## CJam - 50

This is a plain ASCII solution that uses HTTP requests (this is allowed in the question):

```
"aj21.com/"r+g
```

On the server there are 9 plain-text files named 1, 2, ..., 9, each containing the corresponding word.

Total size: 14 + 3 ("one") + 3 ("two") + 5 + 4 + 4 + 3 + 5 + 5 + 4 = 50.
It can be golfed more by using a shorter domain.

The online interpreter doesn't support HTTP requests, so the program needs to be run using the [java interpreter](http://sf.net/p/cjam).

Answer (score 2):

## Batch - 86

Far shorter than the other batch answer, and actually surprisingly competitive.

```
for /f "tokens=%1" %%1 in ("one two three four five six seven eight nine") do echo>%%1
```

Used as `filename.bat number`, and the output is in the form of a file with the name of the correct number.

Answer (score 2):

### BASH 9

shameless Linux-replica of [cousincoicane's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32298/13171)

```
spd-say 1
```

speaks out one

Comment: Wouldn't this only work if the input was 1?

Comment: @Chipperyman it works for any number

Comment: Limit, but clever !

Comment: This misses the input.

Comment: @nicolasbarbulesco yes. but there were many other answers that miss input, so I went ahead with this.

Comment: @Chipperyman — You have accepted this answer, missing the input, but you have rejected the answer by CousinCocaine because it misses the input. And this answer is a replica of CousinCocaine's answer. This is more than unfair.

Comment: @RegisteredUser — No, it does not work for numbers ≠ 1.

Comment: The other solutions — including mines — would be shorter too if they placed the “input” directly at the target spot.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco It works for every number.have you checked it on a linux system?

Answer (score 2):

## GolfScript, 50 bytes

I wanted to see if I could beat [Quincunx's 51-byte self-contained GolfScript solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32151/convert-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-and-9-to-one-two-three-etc/32154#32154).  Turns out that, with enough tricks, yes, I can — by one byte.

Since one of the tricks I'm using is the use of bytes outside the printable ASCII range, the resulting program is cannot be directly pasted here.  Instead, I'm providing a hex dump of it; users on Unixish systems can use `xxd -r` to reconstruct the actual 50-byte GolfScript program from the hex dump:

```
0000000: 7e6e 270b 97eb 442f e166 9894 9f00 c63c  ~n'...D/.f.....<
0000010: 8128 73a3 9b55 5065 a9fb f06a 2727 ff16  .(s..UPe...j''..
0000020: 277b 6261 7365 7d2f 2b6e 2f3d 7b39 392b  '{base}/+n/={99+
0000030: 7d25                                     }%
```

The basic trick used to generate this program is simple: I compress the long string literal that makes up most of Quincunx's code by subtracting 99 (the ASCII code of the letter `c`) from the character values, interpreting the resulting values as a number in base 22 (enough to encode the letters up to `x`) and then re-encode the resulting number in base 255 to produce the unprintable byte string that makes up most of the first half of my program.  The rest of the program then reverses this process, decoding the string back into something printable.

(Since the lowest letter actually present in the number names is `e`, I could've shortened the byte string further by subtracting 101 from the ASCII codes and using base 20.  However, subtracting 101 would've mapped the letter `o` to a newline, which I'm using as the number delimiter because it's conveniently available as the built-in constant `n` in GolfScript.  Working around that would cost me more than the one byte that using a lower base would save.  Using the offset 99 leaves the newline corresponding to the letter `m`, which is conveniently absent from the number names.)

Here's a de-golfed version of the program:

```
~       # eval the input, turning it into a number
n       # push a newline onto the stack; we'll need it later

# this is the byte string encoding the number names:
"\x0B\x97\xEBD/\xE1f\x98\x94\x9F\x00\xC6<\x81(s\xA3\x9BUPe\xA9\xFB\xF0j"

# convert the encoded string from base 255 to base 22
# (and, incidentally, from a string to an array):
"\xFF\x16" {base}/

+       # prepend the newline pushed earlier to the array, re-stringifying it
n/      # split the resulting string at newlines
=       # pick the substring corresponding to the input number
{99+}%  # add 99 to the character values in the chosen substring
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 35 bytes

```
ị“¡5ç“¡Ḃḥ“¡Ị¿“Ɱ9“ƁẆ“¡⁹)“¡°Ṗ“z⁷“¡'Ṡ»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9wd/ejhjmHFpoeXg6mH@5oerhjKYS5u@vQfiDr0cZ1lkDqWOPDXW1giUeNOzXBjEMbHu6cBmRVPWrcDhZQf7hzwaHd////NwcA)

Explanation:

```
 “¡5ç“¡Ḃḥ“¡Ị¿“Ɱ9“ƁẆ“¡⁹)“¡°Ṗ“z⁷“¡'Ṡ» List of numbers 1-9 as words.
ị                                   xth element of y.
```

Answer (score 2):

## APL, 54 bytes

```
⎕⊃↓9 5⍴'ONE  TWO  THREEFOUR FIVE SIX  SEVENEIGHTNINE '
```

Answer (score 1):

### Tcl, 61

Number entered as command line argument

```
lindex {- one two three four five six seven eight nine} $argv
```

Answer (score 1):

## F# - 101

```
printf"%s"["one";"two";"three";"four";"five";"six";"seven";"eight";"nine"].[System.Console.Read()-49]
```

For a newline but 108 bytes, change `printf` to `printfn`.

It's a naïve solution that just fetches the given index of that hardcoded list. I would have loved to use base64 encoding and/or a regex to split a string into an array (so the elements would be separated with  instead of `";"`), but both of those would just make the solution longer, due to namespaces. Why can't they just be in `System` like everything else? :'(

Comment: You could do Console.Read() like I did in the Csharp version.

Comment: @rene ah, didn't know that existed. Thanks! :)

Comment: You don't need the parse...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx  you get an int as return value for the ascii code of the char

Comment: @rene Didn't see that either... Thanks again! xP

Comment: Wait, how does adding a single character make it 124 bytes from 107?

Comment: @nyuszika7h oops, I forgot to update that number earlier. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## Racket / R5RS Scheme: <s>71</s> 68

```scm
(vector-ref'#(z one two three four five six seven eight nine)(read))
```

*It runs in the REPL of R6RS and R7RS with base library loaded too.*

Comment: You can save 3 characters in the Racket code by using `0` (or any other single character) instead of `zero`.

Comment: @nyuszika7h Thanks. I originally though zero was needed and I forgot to remove it from the Racket version.

Comment: @Charles It's done :)

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm not going to win but I just want to participe...

**C++11 172**

```
   #include <iostream>
    int main(){ auto a = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };printf("%s", *(a.begin() + getchar() - '0' - 1));}
```

**Javascript - <s>79 - 69</s> 68**: (run on dev console)

<s>["one", "two", "three", "four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"][prompt()-1]</s>

<s>"one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine".split(',')[prompt()-1]</s>

```
",one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine".split(',')[prompt()]
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++11 - 133

My answer in C++:

```
#include<iostream>
main(){char*n[]={"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"};std::cout<<n[std::cin.get()-'1'];}
```

The total amount of bytes is 133.

Answer (score 1):

### Objective-C - 154 bytes

This one is kind of cheating a little bit because Objective-C has a built in class just for this but I don't see anything in the rules that says I can't do that so here it is!

```
int i;
scanf("%d",&i);
NSNumberFormatter *f=[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:5];
NSString *s=[f stringFromNumber:@(i)];
NSLog(@"%@",s);
```

Comment: This is not cheating. This is what I wanted to do in AppleScript, but I did not find the built-in method I wanted. [So I wrote the method myself.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32225/12943)

Answer (score 1):

**Ruby 68**

```
v=%w(one two three four five six seven eight nine);p v[gets.to_i-1]
```

Would love tips on how to get it down further!

Comment: you can eliminate the declaration of `v` which saves you 4 chars.. that is, `p %w(...)[...]`

Answer (score 1):

## Shell, 42 bytes

```
cat $1
```

This relies on files in the current directory, one for each digit.  The lengths of the files are included in the score:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/n$ ls -l
total 40
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 3 Jun 22 11:39 1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 3 Jun 22 11:40 2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 5 Jun 22 11:40 3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 4 Jun 22 11:40 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 4 Jun 22 11:41 5
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 3 Jun 22 11:41 6
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 5 Jun 22 11:41 7
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 5 Jun 22 11:41 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 4 Jun 22 11:41 9
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 6 Jun 22 11:42 n.sh
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/n$
```

Example Output:

```
$ ./n.sh 4
four$ 
$ ./n.sh 7
seven$ 
$
```

Comment: The names of the files are a key part of the solution. If we count the characters, then the names of the files have to be included. The total length of this solution is 51 (`1one2two3three4four5five6six7seven8eight9ninecat $1`).

Answer (score 1):

### Apple Swift : 143

Not a winner, but my first Code-Golf, so hello everyone!

```
for i in 1..C_ARGC{print(["zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"][String.fromCString(C_ARGV[Int(i)]).toInt()!])}
```

What I like about this is that the lookup table is defined in place in `print` so I could shave a few chars by removing the variable definition for it.

Accepts any number of input arguments, provided that they are separeted with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

### R, 67 characters

```
scan(t='one two three four five six seven eight nine',w='')[scan()]
```

First part creates a vector containing the names, second part subset it according to user input (indices are 1-based in R).

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell (71)

```
PS > "one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine".split(",")[$(read-host)]
```

Works for valid inputs.

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript, <s>94</s> <s>92</s> 84 bytes

```
alert(['one','two','three','four','five','six', 'seven','eight','nine'][prompt()-1])
```

Comment: Explicit cast is useless : `alert(['one','two','three','four','five','six', 'seven','eight','nine'][prompt()-1])`

Comment: You can also abuse of `split` : `alert('0one0two0three0four0five0six0seven0eight0nine'.split(0)[prompt()])` but that is the answer of @nderscore

Answer (score 1):

## C - <s>93</s> <s>91</s> <s>89</s> 88 bytes (thanks Cool Guy)

```
main(x){scanf("%d",&x);write(1,5*--x+"one  two  threefour five six  seveneightnine",5);}
```

Old version with arguments instead of `scanf`:

```
main(int c,char**a){write(1,"one  two  threefour five six  seveneightnine"+*a[1]*5-245,5);}
```

## Cryptic version ([code-trolling](/questions/tagged/code-trolling)?):

This one is somewhat longer but at least no space is wasted on spaces (only tabs and newlines ... and one space in function header).

```
main(int c,char**a){
    *a="039018342675onetwosixfourfivenineseveneightthree";
    c=*(*a+*a[1]-46)-39;
    write(1,c/3*(c-9)-*(*a+c/3-3)+60+*a,c/3);
}
```

Magic sequence `018342675` can be calculated as `x+=6*!(x%3)-1;x%=9;` but in the end I decided to use strings for everything.

Yet another version (different arrangement of numbers, easier to calculate position):

```
main(int c,char**a){
    *a="038146257onefourseventwofiveeightsixninethree";
    c=*(*a+*a[1]-49)-45;
    write(1,*a+c*4+!(c%3)-4,3+c%3);
}
```

Comment: Why not `main(x){...}` instead of `x;main(){...}` in the first program?

Answer (score 1):

## sed 90

It's really a trivial program (the brute force method); I wouldn't have bothered, except that it beats a surprising number of answers here.

```
s/9/nine/
s/8/eight/
s/7/seven/
s/6/six/
s/5/five/
s/4/four/
s/3/three/
s/2/two/
s/1/one/
```

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell 63

```
(-split"X one two three four five six seven eight nine")[$args]
```

(The default delimiter in [Powershell is whitespace](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847811.aspx#CodeSnippetContainerCode_72b2a5d0-3fc0-44a7-9bb4-efa19deb56fe))

Answer (score 1):

**Python 3 + Japanese - 34 characters (52 bytes)**

Not sure if this counts:

```
print('九八七六五四三二一'[-int(input())])
```

Numbers were taken from:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_numerals

Answer (score 1):

## [Sclipting](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Sclipting) (34)

```
껆뭮뉒롴덶묬덆둲뉖넬뉦뭵댢롦늗뉥껇꽩뎂롳뉗뉥닢롥늖덨덂롮늖멥壹坼⓶掘
```

---

This is very straight-forward. Remember the user input is first on the stack.

`껆뭮뉒롴덶묬덆둲뉖넬뉦뭵댢롦늗뉥껇꽩뎂롳뉗뉥닢롥늖덨덂롮늖멥`

- Push the string `",one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine"`

`壹`

- Retrieve the first character from that string (but leave the string on the stack)

`坼`

- Regular expression string-split. Result: `["", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"]`

`⓶`

- Swap the top two elements (so the input is now on top)

`掘`

- Get *n*th element from the list, leaving only the result on the stack.

Comment: Isn't it disallowed to use such languages?

Comment: @reg Why would it be?

Comment: For this reason http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1071/13171

Comment: @RegisteredUser: Sclipting is not designed for any particular challenge. It is, in fact, similar in goal to Golfscript.

Answer (score 1):

**In Java (7 and newer) ; 116 chars**

```java
public class A{public static void main(String[] a){System.out.print(Character.getName(48+Integer.parseInt(a[0])));}}
```

This program takes the input number as command-line argument, and outputs the letters in the console.

*Example :*

- Input : `4`
- Output : `DIGIT FOUR`

Comment: I think the class doesn't need to be public; also, why not just call getName(a[0].charAt(0))? And you don't need a space after []

Answer (score 1):

**In AppleScript ; 53 chars.**

```
say(display dialog""default answer"")'s text returned
```

Here is a nicer version :

```
set n to text returned of (display dialog "?" default answer "")
say n
```

This script takes the input in a dialog. Then it tells the output to the user. The user does not even have to read ! This solution works even for people who are unable to read.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell 75

I know I'm a little late to the party, but thought I might as well:

```haskell
fmap(words"_ One Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight Nine"!!)readLn>>=print
```

Answer (score 1):

### Racket 159 bytes

```
(string-join(map(λ(x)(list-ref(list"zero""one""two""three""four""five""six""seven""eight""nine")(string->number(string x))))(string->list(number->string n))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define(f n)
  (string-join
   (map (λ (x)
          (list-ref [list "zero" "one" "two" "three" "four" "five" "six" "seven" "eight" "nine"]
                    (string->number(string x))))
        (string->list (number->string n)))))
```

Testing:

```
(f 10357)
```

Output:

```
"one zero three five seven"
```

17 bytes can be saved if number is sent enclosed in double quotes:

```
(define(f n)
  (string-join
   (map (λ (x)
          (list-ref [list "zero" "one" "two" "three" "four" "five" "six" "seven" "eight" "nine"]
                    (string->number(string x))))
        (string->list n))))

(f "10357")
"one zero three five seven"
```

Comment: It only has to work for 1-9 but nice answer! This could be extended to write out real english (`10357` -> `ten thousand three hundred fifty seven`)

Answer (score 1):

## Wolfram, 11

There is a function for that of course: `IntegerName`

Answer (score 1):

## Factor, 11 bytes

a builtin: `number>text`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Lexurgy](https://www.lexurgy.com/sc), 79 bytes

```
a:
{\1,\2,\3,\4,\5,\6,\7,\8,\9}=>{one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine}
```

Simple substitution.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
∆ċ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4oiGxIsiLCIiLCIxXG4yXG4zXG40XG41XG42XG43XG44XG45Il0=)

Builtin.

Answer (score 0):

**POSIX SHELL: 68**

Similar to Eric's Bash, without the bashisms (using set to mimick an array using $@) and eval to handle indirection (in bash this could just be `echo ${!A}` without the eval)

```
A=$1
set one two three four five six seven eight nine
eval echo \$$A
```

Comment: In bash you can just use `$X` instead of `echo ${!X}` as long as you use `set` :) If you use set, the curly braces actually cause nothing to happen while returning code 0.

Comment: @eric_lagergren - this is a proper posix implementation though -no bashisms allowed.  Even in bash though the ! is needed for variable indirection to convert the 1 stored in $A into a $1 variable.  Just eval-ing $A will try run 1, eval-ing \$$A will try to run "one" ... the echo is just to print without a "command not found", just because I consider it bad form. (hopefully that's all - at least I don't know of any malicious binaries with spelled out number names)

Comment: The `!` isn't needed http://i.imgur.com/tnivt32.png ... or at least, for whatever reason, I didn't need it. Adding `echo` removes the `bash: xxxx: command not found` but adds 4 .

Comment: @eric_lagergren - Yeah, _that_ works ... in interactive mode only.  Now put it in an actual script. ... can't add it to an rc file because it clobbers your args.  Isn't working without real bash arrays fun?

Comment: As long as I'm not held accountable for it (except in perhaps a good way) I *love* writing hacky code :P

Answer (score 0):

## Rebol - 58

```
pick[one two three four five six seven eight nine]do input
```

Example from Rebol console:

```
>> pick[one two three four five six seven eight nine]do input           
9
== nine
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python

here is a simple answer. In python, if you have a key-val mapping pair, you use a dict. this program waits for an input, (0-9) and converts it

```
n={
1:'one',2:'two',3:'three',4:'four',5:'five',6:'six',7:'seven',8:'eight',9:'nine',0:'zero'}
print n.get(int(raw_input()))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby - 66

```
$><<%w[a one two three four five six seven eight nine][gets.to_i]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Zozotez Lisp](http://sylwester.no/zozotez/): <s>[122](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/32186/revisions)</s> 78

```lisp
((\(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)(p(e(r))))'one'two'three'four'five'six'seven'eight'nine)
```

*Zozotez is a LISP-1 interpreter written in [Extended BrainFuck](http://sylwester.no/ebf/). It's only data types are symbols and cons and supports first class functions and macros*

Answer (score 0):

## [Extended BrainFuck](http://sylwester.no/ebf/): 130

```
{z(-))}{b&z)<(-}+>,49-(-(-(-(-(-(-(-((-)<-|<nine<&z<(-|<eight<&b
|<seven<&b|<six<&b|<five<&z)<(-|<four<&b|<three<&b|<two<&b|<one<&z
```

*EBF is a superset of [BrainFuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) but it has not it's own runtime. It compiles to pure BrainFuck.*

Answer (score 0):

**Forth (gforth)**

```
36 base ! nine eight seven six five four three two one 0
```

Usage:

```
1 pick . ONE  ok
2 pick . TWO  ok
3 pick . THREE  ok
4 pick . FOUR  ok
5 pick . FIVE  ok
6 pick . SIX  ok
7 pick . SEVEN  ok
8 pick . EIGHT  ok
9 pick . NINE  ok
```

where `ok` is printed by the interpreter.
In fact, I do not know how to count characters in this. One might even say that this is not a program.

Answer (score 0):

### swipl: 104 bytes

```
get_char(C),number_codes(X,[C]),nth0(X,[o,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten],Y),write(Y).
```

### Brainfuck: 672 bytes

```
+>,-------------------------------------------------[-[-[-[-[-[-[-[[-]+
[------->++<]>.-----.+++++.---------.[-]<[-]>[-]]<[[-]--[----->+<]>-.++
++.--.+.++++++++++++.[-]<[-]>[-]][-]<[-]>[-]]<[[-]+[--------->++<]>+.++
++[->+++<]>.[--->+<]>-.+[->+++<]>.+++++++++.[-]<[-]>[-]][-]<[-]>[-]]<[[
-]+[--------->++<]>+.----------.-[--->+<]>.[-]<[-]>[-]][-]<[-]>[-]]<[[-
]--[----->+<]>.+++.[->++++++<]>.+[->+++<]>.[-]<[-]>[-]][-]<[-]>[-]]<[[-
]--[----->+<]>.+++++++++.++++++.---.[-]<[-]>[-]][-]<[-]>[-]]<[[-]------
--[-->+++<]>.------------.++++++++++.-------------..[-]<[-]>[-]][-]<[-]
>[-]]<[[-]--------[-->+++<]>.+++.--------.[-]<[-]>[-]][-]<[-]>[-]]<[[-]
+[------->++<]>+.-.---------.[-]]
```

Comment: IMHO and according to the rules the content of "swipl" should be counted, too. Technically it's a request to another program or am I wrong?

Comment: Ups!. I'll change it. Thanks @german_guy

Comment: @german_guy changed!

Comment: @ProgramFOX I'm sorry I don't understand you. Now it is using _only_ swipl.

Comment: @rpax Ah, now I see. I thought you were only using bash now. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell : 89

```
do x<-readLn;print$[[],"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"]!!x
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP 5.5 (62)

```
<?=[0,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine][$argv[1]];
```

If you read from standard input it goes up to 66 characters.

```
<?=[0,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine][fgetc(STDIN)];
```

Answer (score 0):

## Bash, 64

```
d=(z one two three four five six seven eight nine)
echo ${d[$1]}
```

Takes the first argument as a number and uses it as an array index to print the corresponding word.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 34 / 28

For this code to work, you have to install `num2words` module. Also thanks to @undergroundmonorail for his suggestion.

```
import num2words
num2words(input())
```

If `input()` is not necessary , and user is allowed to enter number directly into code, then

```
import num2words
num2words(3)
```

will also work.

Comment: Why not `num2words(raw_input())`? Or even `input()`, since it's guaranteed to be a number?

Comment: @undergroundmonorail Thanks. didn't knew about it. I'm not too good in python.

Answer (score 0):

## C, <s>92</s> 89 bytes Japanese(Hiragana , Katakana)

Hiragana (ひらがな)

```
h(n){char*h="いちに　さんし　ご　ろくななはちきゅ";printf("%.6s%s",h+--n*6,n^9?"":"う");}
```

Katakana (カタカナ)

```
k(n){char*k="イチニ　サンシ　ゴ　ロクシチハチキュ";printf("%.6s%s",k+--n*6,n^9?"":"ウ");}
```

http://sp.cis.iwate-u.ac.jp/sp/lesson/j/doc/numbers.html

[ideone it!](http://ideone.com/4d3kGw)

Comment: Does this actually output in japanese?

Comment: Yes. [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/4d3kGw) test. @Eʀɪᴋ ᴛʜᴇ Gᴏʟғᴇʀ

Answer (score 0):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), <s>80</s> 79 bytes

```
/_/\/\///0/zero_1/one_2/two_3/three_4/four_5/five_6/six_7/seven_8/eight_9/nine/
```

Append the number at the end of the code (this is ///'s input).

Comment: Nine `//` is just enough for `/_/\/\//` to save a byte.

Comment: @MartinEnder As I told you in another comment, this won't work, because then `_` will evaluate to `\/\/`, not `//`. If you want to prove it works, please comment a link to an example using this.

Comment: http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=L18vXC9cLy8vMC96ZXJvXzEvb25lXzIvdHdvXzMvdGhyZWVfNC9mb3VyXzUvZml2ZV82L3NpeF83L3NldmVuXzgvZWlnaHRfOS9uaW5lLwowIDEgMiAzIDQgNSA2IDcgOCA5&input=

Comment: @MartinEnder So *that* is the reason I've had problems with forward slashes (`/`) in the past...

Answer (score 0):

## [Sprects](https://dinod123.neocities.org/interpreter.html), 61 bytes

```
#<INPUT>#9nine#8eight#7seven#6six#5five#4four#3three#2two#1one#0zero
```

Replace `<INPUT>` with the number, because Sprects does not have any other form of input (bytecount is without the "input".)