# Sum up a number in words

Tags: code-golf

Here's a simple one.

In the *shortest code possible*, given an arbitrary number such as `567421`, print it out in words:

```
five
six
seven
four
two
one
```

You may assume the input is an integer that is already provided in a one-letter variable such as `n`.

Comment: I see, sorry about that, didn't find those when i was searching.

Comment: Though both possible duplicates ask something slightly different.

Comment: In particular the only change you need to make to answers of the duplicate mentioned by undergroundmonorail is to call the code you already have for each digit of the input.

Answer (score 2):

Python

```
for i in `n`:print' ottffssennwhoiieiieoruvxvgn  ere ehe  e   nt'[int(i)::9]
```

"Inspired" by https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32156/18638