# Basic Latin character name to character

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity

Let's get back to basics!

- Your code, a complete program or function, must convert the official Unicode name of a printable Basic Latin character into the corresponding character. For example, for the input `LOW LINE` your code must output `_`.
- You only need to take a single character name as input.
- You cannot use any preexisting function or library, built-in or otherwise, which offers any logic relating specifically to Unicode character names (e.g. Python's `unicodedata`, Java's `Character.getName`, and so on.)
- For input other than one of these names, any behavior is acceptable.

This is code golf: shortest code in bytes wins.

To avoid any ambiguity, this is the full set of official character names we'll be using (borrowed from [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57143/print-the-character-names)):

```
     SPACE
!    EXCLAMATION MARK
"    QUOTATION MARK
#    NUMBER SIGN
$    DOLLAR SIGN
%    PERCENT SIGN
&    AMPERSAND
'    APOSTROPHE
(    LEFT PARENTHESIS
)    RIGHT PARENTHESIS
*    ASTERISK
+    PLUS SIGN
,    COMMA
-    HYPHEN-MINUS
.    FULL STOP
/    SOLIDUS
0    DIGIT ZERO
1    DIGIT ONE
2    DIGIT TWO
3    DIGIT THREE
4    DIGIT FOUR
5    DIGIT FIVE
6    DIGIT SIX
7    DIGIT SEVEN
8    DIGIT EIGHT
9    DIGIT NINE
:    COLON
;    SEMICOLON
<    LESS-THAN SIGN
=    EQUALS SIGN
>    GREATER-THAN SIGN
?    QUESTION MARK
@    COMMERCIAL AT
A    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
B    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER B
C    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
D    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D
E    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
F    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER F
G    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER G
H    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER H
I    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
J    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER J
K    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER K
L    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
M    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER M
N    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
O    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
P    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER P
Q    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Q
R    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
S    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
T    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
U    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U
V    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER V
W    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER W
X    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER X
Y    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Y
Z    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z
[    LEFT SQUARE BRACKET
\    REVERSE SOLIDUS
]    RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET
^    CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT
_    LOW LINE
`    GRAVE ACCENT
a    LATIN SMALL LETTER A
b    LATIN SMALL LETTER B
c    LATIN SMALL LETTER C
d    LATIN SMALL LETTER D
e    LATIN SMALL LETTER E
f    LATIN SMALL LETTER F
g    LATIN SMALL LETTER G
h    LATIN SMALL LETTER H
i    LATIN SMALL LETTER I
j    LATIN SMALL LETTER J
k    LATIN SMALL LETTER K
l    LATIN SMALL LETTER L
m    LATIN SMALL LETTER M
n    LATIN SMALL LETTER N
o    LATIN SMALL LETTER O
p    LATIN SMALL LETTER P
q    LATIN SMALL LETTER Q
r    LATIN SMALL LETTER R
s    LATIN SMALL LETTER S
t    LATIN SMALL LETTER T
u    LATIN SMALL LETTER U
v    LATIN SMALL LETTER V
w    LATIN SMALL LETTER W
x    LATIN SMALL LETTER X
y    LATIN SMALL LETTER Y
z    LATIN SMALL LETTER Z
{    LEFT CURLY BRACKET
|    VERTICAL LINE
}    RIGHT CURLY BRACKET
~    TILDE
```

Comment: Does the program only need to handle one character name?  For example, should `COLON COLON` output `::` , or undefined behaviour?

Comment: Edited to clarify.

Comment: Why is `String.fromCharCode` forbidden?

Comment: Whoops, I misunderstood what that function does.

Comment: How must we handle invalid input, like `CLON` ?

Comment: See the fourth bullet point.

Comment: Invalid Perl 5 (breaks rule #3): `perl -lpe '$_=eval"\"\\N{$_}\""'` = 20 + 2 = 22

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## IA-32 machine code, <s>161</s> <s>160</s> 122 bytes

Hexdump of the code:

```
33 c0 6b c0 59 0f b6 11 03 c2 b2 71 f6 f2 c1 e8
08 41 80 79 01 00 75 ea e8 39 00 00 00 08 2c 5e
4a bd a3 cd c5 90 09 46 04 06 14 40 3e 3d 5b 23
60 5e 3f 2d 31 32 29 25 2e 3c 7e 36 39 34 33 30
21 2f 26 7d 7c 2c 3b 7b 2a 37 5d 22 35 20 3a 28
5c 27 2b 38 5f 24 5a 3c 34 74 17 3c 1a 74 16 33
c9 86 c4 0f a3 0a 14 00 41 fe cc 75 f6 8a 44 02
0e c3 8a 01 c3 8a 01 04 20 c3
```

This code uses some hashing. By some brute-force search, I found that the following hash function can be applied to the bytes of the input string:

```
int x = 0;
while (s[1])
{
    x = (x * 89 + *s) % 113;
    ++s;
}
```

It multiplies `x` by 89, adds the next byte (ASCII-code), and takes a remainder modulo 113. It does this on all bytes of the input string except the last one, so e.g. `LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A` and `LATIN CAPITAL LETTER X` give the same hash code.

This hash function has no collisions, and the output is in the range 0...113 (actually, by luck, the range is even narrower: 3...108).

The hash values of all relevant strings don't fill that space completely, so I decided to use this to compress the hash table. I added a "skip" table (112 bits), which contains 0 if the corresponding place in the hash table is empty, and 1 otherwise. This table converts a hash value into a "compressed" index, which can be used to address a dense LUT.

The strings `LATIN CAPITAL LETTER` and `LATIN SMALL LETTER` give hash codes 52 and 26; they are handled separately. Here is a C code for that:

```
char find(const char* s)
{
    int hash = 0;
    while (s[1])
    {
        hash = (hash * 89 + *s) % 113;
        ++s;
    }

    if (hash == 52)
        return *s;
    if (hash == 26)
        return *s + 32;

    int result_idx = 0;
    int bit = 0;
    uint32_t skip[] = {0x4a5e2c08, 0xc5cda3bd, 0x04460990, 0x1406};
    do {
        if (skip[bit / 32] & (1 << bit % 32))
            ++result_idx;
        ++bit;
    } while (--hash);

    return "@>=[#`^?-12)%.<~69430!/&}|,;{*7]\"5 :(\\'+8_$"[result_idx];
}
```

The corresponding assembly language code (MS Visual Studio inline-assembly syntax):

```
_declspec(naked) char _fastcall find(char* s)
{
    _asm {
        xor eax, eax;
    mycalc:
        imul eax, eax, 89;
        movzx edx, [ecx];
        add eax, edx;
        mov dl, 113;
        div dl;
        shr eax, 8;
        inc ecx;
        cmp byte ptr [ecx + 1], 0;
        jne mycalc;

        call mycont;
        // skip table
        _asm _emit 0x08 _asm _emit 0x2c _asm _emit 0x5e _asm _emit 0x4a;
        _asm _emit 0xbd _asm _emit 0xa3 _asm _emit 0xcd _asm _emit 0xc5;
        _asm _emit 0x90 _asm _emit 0x09 _asm _emit 0x46 _asm _emit 0x04;
        _asm _emit 0x06 _asm _emit 0x14;
        // char table
        _asm _emit '@' _asm _emit '>' _asm _emit '=' _asm _emit '[';
        _asm _emit '#' _asm _emit '`' _asm _emit '^' _asm _emit '?';
        _asm _emit '-' _asm _emit '1' _asm _emit '2' _asm _emit ')';
        _asm _emit '%' _asm _emit '.' _asm _emit '<' _asm _emit '~';
        _asm _emit '6' _asm _emit '9' _asm _emit '4' _asm _emit '3';
        _asm _emit '0' _asm _emit '!' _asm _emit '/' _asm _emit '&';
        _asm _emit '}' _asm _emit '|' _asm _emit ',' _asm _emit ';';
        _asm _emit '{' _asm _emit '*' _asm _emit '7' _asm _emit ']';
        _asm _emit '"' _asm _emit '5' _asm _emit ' ' _asm _emit ':';
        _asm _emit '(' _asm _emit '\\' _asm _emit '\'' _asm _emit '+';
        _asm _emit '8' _asm _emit '_' _asm _emit '$';

    mycont:
        pop edx;
        cmp al, 52;
        je capital_letter;
        cmp al, 26;
        je small_letter;

        xor ecx, ecx;
        xchg al, ah;
    decode_hash_table:
        bt [edx], ecx;
        adc al, 0;
        inc ecx;
        dec ah;
        jnz decode_hash_table;

        mov al, [edx + eax + 14];
        ret;

    capital_letter:
        mov al, [ecx];
        ret;

    small_letter:
        mov al, [ecx];
        add al, 32;
        ret;
    }
}
```

Some noteworthy implementation details:

- It uses a `CALL` instruction to get a pointer to the code, where the hard-coded table resides. In 64-bit mode, it could use the register `rip` instead.
- It uses the [`BT`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Test) instruction to access the skip table
- It manages to do the work using only 3 registers `eax`, `ecx`, `edx`, which can be clobbered - so there is no need to save and restore registers
- When decoding the hash table, it uses `al` and `ah` carefully, so that at the right place `ah` is decreased to 0, and the whole `eax` register can be used as a LUT index

Answer (score 17):

## JavaScript ES6, 228 <s>236 247 257 267 274 287</s>

Note: 7 chars saved thx @ev3commander

Note 2: **better than JAPT** after 7 major edits,

```js
n=>n<'L'?"XC!DO$MP&OS'SK*N--FU.ZE0TW2HR3OU4FI5IX6EI8NI9EM;LS=R->IA@MF^AV`MM,NE1EN7LO:".replace(/(..)./g,(c,s)=>~n.search(s)?n=c[2]:0)&&n:'~  / ;  |?"\\ ) }]_+ #% < ( {['[(n<'Q')*13+n.length-(n>'T')-4]||n[21]||n[19].toLowerCase()
```

Run the snippet to test

```js
F=n=>
  n<'L'?"XC!DO$MP&OS'SK*N--FU.ZE0TW2HR3OU4FI5IX6EI8NI9EM;LS=R->IA@MF^AV`MM,NE1EN7LO:"
  .replace(/(..)./g,(c,s)=>~n.search(s)?n=c[2]:0)&&n:
  '~  / ;  |?"\\ ) }]_+ #% < ( {['[(n<'Q')*13+n.length-(n>'T')-4]
  ||n[21]||n[19].toLowerCase()

//TEST
console.log=x=>O.innerHTML+=x+'\n'
;[
['&','AMPERSAND'],
['\'','APOSTROPHE'],
['*','ASTERISK'],
['^','CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT'],
[':','COLON'],
[',','COMMA'],
['@','COMMERCIAL AT'],
['8','DIGIT EIGHT'],
['5','DIGIT FIVE'],
['4','DIGIT FOUR'],
['9','DIGIT NINE'],
['1','DIGIT ONE'],
['7','DIGIT SEVEN'],
['6','DIGIT SIX'],
['3','DIGIT THREE'],
['2','DIGIT TWO'],
['0','DIGIT ZERO'],
['$','DOLLAR SIGN'],
['=','EQUALS SIGN'],
['!','EXCLAMATION MARK'],
['.','FULL STOP'],
['`','GRAVE ACCENT'],
['>','GREATER-THAN SIGN'],
['-','HYPHEN-MINUS'],
['A','LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A'],
['B','LATIN CAPITAL LETTER B'],
['C','LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C'],
['D','LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D'],
['E','LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E'],
['F','LATIN CAPITAL LETTER F'],
['G','LATIN CAPITAL LETTER G'],
['H','LATIN CAPITAL LETTER H'],
['I','LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I'],
['J','LATIN CAPITAL LETTER J'],
['K','LATIN CAPITAL LETTER K'],
['L','LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L'],
['M','LATIN CAPITAL LETTER M'],
['N','LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N'],
['O','LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O'],
['P','LATIN CAPITAL LETTER P'],
['Q','LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Q'],
['R','LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R'],
['S','LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S'],
['T','LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T'],
['U','LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U'],
['V','LATIN CAPITAL LETTER V'],
['W','LATIN CAPITAL LETTER W'],
['X','LATIN CAPITAL LETTER X'],
['Y','LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Y'],
['Z','LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z'],
['a','LATIN SMALL LETTER A'],
['b','LATIN SMALL LETTER B'],
['c','LATIN SMALL LETTER C'],
['d','LATIN SMALL LETTER D'],
['e','LATIN SMALL LETTER E'],
['f','LATIN SMALL LETTER F'],
['g','LATIN SMALL LETTER G'],
['h','LATIN SMALL LETTER H'],
['i','LATIN SMALL LETTER I'],
['j','LATIN SMALL LETTER J'],
['k','LATIN SMALL LETTER K'],
['l','LATIN SMALL LETTER L'],
['m','LATIN SMALL LETTER M'],
['n','LATIN SMALL LETTER N'],
['o','LATIN SMALL LETTER O'],
['p','LATIN SMALL LETTER P'],
['q','LATIN SMALL LETTER Q'],
['r','LATIN SMALL LETTER R'],
['s','LATIN SMALL LETTER S'],
['t','LATIN SMALL LETTER T'],
['u','LATIN SMALL LETTER U'],
['v','LATIN SMALL LETTER V'],
['w','LATIN SMALL LETTER W'],
['x','LATIN SMALL LETTER X'],
['y','LATIN SMALL LETTER Y'],
['z','LATIN SMALL LETTER Z'],
['{','LEFT CURLY BRACKET'],
['(','LEFT PARENTHESIS'],
['[','LEFT SQUARE BRACKET'],
['<','LESS-THAN SIGN'],
['_','LOW LINE'],
['#','NUMBER SIGN'],
['%','PERCENT SIGN'],
['+','PLUS SIGN'],
['?','QUESTION MARK'],
['"','QUOTATION MARK'],
['\\','REVERSE SOLIDUS'],
['}','RIGHT CURLY BRACKET'],
[')','RIGHT PARENTHESIS'],
[']','RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET'],
[';','SEMICOLON'],
['/','SOLIDUS'],
[' ','SPACE'],
['~','TILDE'],
['|','VERTICAL LINE'],
].forEach(t=>{
  var r=F(t[1]),ok=r==t[0]
  //if (!ok) // uncomment to see just errors
  console.log(r+' ('+t[0]+') '+t[1]+(ok?' OK':' ERROR'))
})
console.log('DONE')
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: Just... how? Well done.

Comment: Actually, besides the alphabet, there is no char starting with "LA"

Comment: @ev3commander yes, but here I manage LAT, RIG and LEF and 2 chars seems too few, having LEFT and LESS

Comment: Ohh. I just skimmed and didn't see the RIG/LEF part.

Comment: @ev3commander on second thought you have a point! I can merge handling LESS and LEFT and save 4 bytes. Thx

Answer (score 10):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt), 230 bytes

```
V=U¯2;Ug21 ªU<'R©Ug19 v ªV¥"DI"©`ze¿twâ¿¿¿¿e¿i`u bUs6,8)/2ªUf"GN" ©"<>+=$#%"g`¤grp¤qºnupe`u bV /2 ªUf"T " ©"[]\{}()"g"QSUCAP"bUg6) ªUf" M" ©"!\"?"g"COE"bUg2) ªV¥"CO"©",:@"g"ANE"bUg4) ª" &'*-./\\;~^`_|"g`spaµpÂ¿è±¢¿Èögrlove`u bV /2
```

Each `¿` represents an unprintable Unicode char. [Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=Vj1VrzI7VWcyMSCqVTwnUqlVZzE5IHYgqlalIkRJIqlgemWNdHfiBwOHoGWIaWB1IGJVczYsOCkvMqpVZiJHTiIgqSI8Pis9JCMlImdgpGdycKRxum51cGVgdSBiViAvMiCqVWYiVCAiIKkiW11ce30oKSJnIlFTVUNBUCJiVWc2KSCqVWYiIE0iIKkiIVwiPyJnIkNPRSJiVWcyKSCqVqUiQ08iqSIsOkAiZyJBTkUiYlVnNCkgqiIgJicqLS4vXFw7fl5gX3wiZ2BzcGG1cMKX6LGiDMj2Z3Jsb3ZlYHUgYlYgLzI=&input=IlJJR0hUIENVUkxZIEJSQUNLRVQi)

Ungolfed:

```
V=Us0,2;Ug21 ||U<'R&&Ug19 v ||V=="DI"&&"zeontwthfofisiseeini"u bUs6,8)/2||Uf"GN" &&"<>+=$#%"g"legrpleqdonupe"u bV /2 ||Uf"T " &&"[]\{}()"g"QSUCAP"bUg6) ||Uf" M" &&"!\"?"g"COE"bUg2) ||V=="CO"&&",:@"g"ANE"bUg4) ||" &'*-./\\;~^`_|"g"spamapashyfusoreseticigrlove"u bV /2
```

This was really fun. I've split up the character names into several large chunks:

#### 0. Take first two letters

`V=Us0,2;` sets variable `V` to the first two letters of `U`, the input string. This will come in handy later.

#### 1. Capital letters

This is the easiest: the capital letters are the only ones that have a character at position 21, which all happen to be the correct letter and case. Thus, `Ug21` is sufficient.

#### 2. Lowercase letters

Another fairly easy one; the only other name that has a character at position 19 is `RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET`, so we check if the name is comes before `R` with `U<'R`, then if it is (`&&`), we take the 19th char with `Ug19` and cast it to lowercase with `v`.

#### 3. Digits

These names all start with `DI` (and fortunately, none of the others), so if `V=="DI"`, we can turn it into a digit. The first letters of some of the digits' names are the same, but the first two letters are sufficient. Combining these into one string, we get `ZEONTWTHFOFISISEEINI`. Now we can just take the index `b` of the first two chars in the digit's name with `Us6,8)`and divide by two.

#### 4. `SIGN`

There are seven names that contain `SIGN`:

```
<    LESS-THAN SIGN
>    GREATER-THAN SIGN
+    PLUS SIGN
=    EQUALS SIGN
$    DOLLAR SIGN
#    NUMBER SIGN
%    PERCENT SIGN
```

First we check that it the name contains the word `SIGN`. It turns out `GN` is sufficient; `Uf"GN"` returns all instances of `GN` in the name, which is `null` if it contains 0 instances, and thus gets skipped.

Now, using the same technique as with the digits, we combine the first two letters into a string `LEGRPLEQDONUPE`, then take the index and divide by two. This results an a number from `0-6`, which we can use to take the corresponding character from the string `<>+=$#%`.

#### 5. `MARK`

There are three characters that contain `MARK`:

```
!    EXCLAMATION MARK
"    QUOTATION MARK
?    QUESTION MARK
```

Here we use the same technique as with `SIGN`.  `M` is enough to differentiate these three from the others. To translate to a symbol, this time checking one letter is enough: the character at position 2 is different for all three characters. This means we don't have to divide by two when choosing the correct character.

#### 6. `LEFT/RIGHT`

This group contains the brackets and parentheses, `[]{}()`. It would be really complicated to capture both `LEFT` and `RIGHT`, but fortunately, they all contain the string `T` . We check this with the same technique as we did with `SIGN`. To translate to a symbol, as with `MARK`, checking one letter is enough; the character at position 6 is unique for all six.

#### 7. `CO`

The rest of the chars are pretty unique, but not unique enough. Three of them start with `CO`: `COMMA`, `COLON`, and `COMMERCIAL AT`. We use exactly the same technique as we did with the brackets, choosing the proper symbol based on the character at position 4 (`A`, `N`, or `E`).

#### 8. Everything else

By now, the first two characters are different for every name. We combine them all into one big string `SPAMAPASHYFUSORESETICIGRLOVE` and map each pair to its corresponding char in  `` &'*-./\;~^`_| ``.

#### 9. Final steps

Each of the parts returns an empty string or `null` if it's not the correct one, so we can link them all from left to right with `||`. The `||` operator returns the left argument if it's truthy, and the right argument otherwise. Japt also has implicit output, so whatever the result, it is automatically sent to the output box.

Questions, comments, and suggestions welcome!

Comment: Great answer and great explanation. But you forgot to mention the handling or MARK (!?") in the explanation

Comment: @edc65 Whoops, thanks! I've added in a section on `MARK` chars.

Comment: `spamapashyfusoreseticigrlove` = *Spam a pashy for so reset icy girl love* ... +1

Comment: No, that's very much still golfed.

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript, <s>501</s> <s>499</s> <s>469</s> <s>465</s> <s>451</s> 430 bytes

```
a=prompt();c="5SACEgEARKeQARKbNIGNbDIGNcPIGN9AANDaAPHEgLSIShRSIS8AISK9PIGN5CMMAcHNUS9FTOP7SDUSaDERO9DONE9DTWObDREEaDOURaDIVE9DSIXbDVENbDGHTaDINE5CLON9SLONeLIGNbEIGNhGIGNdQARKdC ATjLKETfRDUSkRKEThCENT8LINEcGENTiLKETdVINEjRKET5TLDE".match(/.{5}/g).indexOf(a.length.toString(36)+a[0]+a.slice(-3));if(c>=33)c+=26;if(c>=65)c+=26;alert(a.length==20&&a[0]=="L"?a.slice(-1).toLowerCase():a.length>21?a.slice(-1):String.fromCharCode(32+c))
```

## Explanation:

That long string is a compressed list. `a.length.toString(36)+a[0]+a.slice(-3)` determines how, if at all, the string will be represented in the list. Also, special logic for letters. (with strings, `a[0]` is a builtin shorthand for `a.charAt(0)`, by the way)

Comment: If you replaced `_` with `+`, you could Base64-compress the list.

Comment: @ETHproductions base64 makes things _longer_, not shorter.

Comment: @ETHproductions Does Javascript *have* Base64?

Comment: @SuperJedi224 Yes it does, but Blacklight is correct unless the base 64 is replacing a number that could have been expressed in a lower base, especially binary.

Comment: You can use `btoa("abc")` to compress text by 25% (as long as it is valid base-64 text, which it would be after replacing `_` with `-`), then `atob("compressed stuff")` in your actual code.

Comment: If you have a string containing only base64 symbols, you can use base64 decoding to obtain a string of chars in range 0..255 that will be shorter. It's difficult to manage here at SO because some chars (code 0..31 and 128...159) are not handled by SO editor

Comment: atob compression example http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32151/convert-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-and-9-to-one-two-three-etc/32163#32163

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 237 bytes

Get the hash of the string and modulo divide it by 535. Subsequently convert it to a unicode character with that number. The position of the unicode character in a precompiled list of unicode characters is subsequently converted to the ascii character.

```
print chr(u"""ǶŀȎdȊÏöǖIhȏƜǓǱǠƣƚǆƩC+ĶÅĠěóƋŎªƱĳůŰűŪūŬŭŶŷŸŹŲųŴŵžſƀƁźŻżŽƆƇƈŖÐŗǀǼǿǾǹǸǻǺȅȄȇȆȁȀȃȂǭǬǯǮǩǨǫǪǵǴǷNȌ~B""".index(unichr(hash(raw_input())%535))+32)
```

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell, <s>603</s> <s>547</s> 464 bytes

```
$a=-split$args
$b=switch -W($a[0]){
"LEFT"{switch -w($a[1]){"C*"{"{"}"P*"{"("}"S*"{"["}}}
"RI*"{switch -w($a[1]){"C*"{"}"}"P*"{")"}"S*"{"]"}}}
"LA*"{("$($a[3])".ToLower(),$a[3])[$a[1]-like"C*"]}
"DI*"{@{ONE=1;TWO=2;THREE=3;FOUR=4;FIVE=5;SIX=6;SEVEN=7;EIGHT=8;NINE=9;ZERO="0"}[$a[1]]}
"COMME*"{"@"}
"APO*"{"'"}
}
$c='COM,LES<GRA`GRE>QUE?QUO"COL:REV\LOW_EXC!EQU=DOL$AMP&AST*PER%PLU+SEM;SOL/SPA CIR^HYP-FUL.NUM#TIL~VER|'
($b,$c[$c.IndexOf($a[0][0..2]-join'')+3])[!$b]
```

(`LineFeed` counts the same one byte as `;`, so I'll leave the breaks in for readability)

<sub>Edit 1 - Took many elements out of the switch statement and instead populated a hashtable for lookups.</sub>

<sub>Edit 2 - Oh yeah ... indexing into a string, that's the way to go ...</sub>

Essentially takes the input, splits it on spaces, and does a wildcard `switch` on the first word to filter out the goofy ones. Sets the result of that to `$b`. If `$b` doesn't exist, the string `$c` gets evaluated on the first three letters of the first word and outputs the character immediately following, otherwise we output `$b`.

Some tricks include the `LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R` which indexes into an array based on whether the second word is `CAPITAL`, and outputs the corresponding uppercase/lowercase letter. The other "trick" is for the `DIGIT`s, by indexing into a hashtable. Note that it's not shorter to do the same index-into-a-string trick here (it's actually longer by one byte).

Comment: I'm beating you again.

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript, <s>416</s> <s>411</s> 389 bytes

```
l=(E)=>{return E=E.replace(/LA.*N|BR.*T|SIGN|MARK| |TION/g,"").replace(/(.).*(.{3})/,"$1$2"),E.match("CER")?E[3]:E.match("SER")?E[3].toLowerCase():(a="SACE EAMA!QOTA\"NBER#DLAR$PENT%AAND&APHE'AISK*PLUS+CMMA,HNUS-FTOP.SDUS/CLON:SLON;LHAN<EALS=GHAN>QUES?CLAT@RDUS\\CENT^LINE_GENT`VINE|LSIS(RSIS)LARE[RARE]LRLY{RRLY}TLDE~DERO0DONE1DTWO2DREE3DOUR4DIVE5DSIX6DVEN7DGHT8DINE9",a[a.indexOf(E)+4])}
```

This is a more readable format(explanation coming later):

```
function l(k){
    k=k.replace(/LA.*N|BR.*T|SIGN|MARK| |TION/g,'').replace(/(.).*(.{3})/,'$1$2')
    if(k.match('CER')) return k[3];
    if(k.match('SER')) return k[3].toLowerCase();
    a="SACE EAMA!QOTA\"NBER#DLAR$PENT%AAND&APHE'AISK*PLUS+CMMA,HNUS-FTOP.SDUS/CLON:SLON;LHAN<EALS=GHAN>QUES?CLAT@RDUS\\CENT^LINE_GENT`VINE|LSIS(RSIS)LARE[RARE]LRLY{RRLY}TLDE~DERO0DONE1DTWO2DREE3DOUR4DIVE5DSIX6DVEN7DGHT8DINE9"
    return a[a.indexOf(k)+4];
}
```

Minus 5 bytes from combining key and value strings.

**Explanation:** The regular expressions on the first line reduce the inputs into unique 4 character keys. Note that uniqueness is only guaranteed for the specific set of names specified in the challenge, and duplicates would be very common for normal English! Even for this challenge, I had to remove common words like bracket and sign to get a unique set.

To return the character, I check to see if it's a latin character by check for the strings "SER" and "cer", and return the last character of the input, in lowercase for ser.

For everything else, I refer to a string that contains all of the 4 character keys, followed by the correct character. I then use indexof and <s>substring</s> character indices to pull and return the character.

**Edit:** Used more wildcards to reduce regex size, replaced substr with character indices and shaved off antoher twenty chars. Rule sticklers will note that this final update is posted after the challenge has ended, however I don't think it changed my ranking. This is just practice for a novice.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 148 bytes

```py
lambda s:chr(83-b'gfhtg\32}urgx_}3qeo|e~cwu~S~q~I,vqG\34jc}d*9~~_L|p~~~~~JJy'[sum(b'  !" *1! "2;D$# ! # !!( '[ord(c)%25]-32for c in s[:-1])]+ord(s[-1]))
```

For your viewing convenience, I’ve replaced two non-printable bytes with the octal escape codes `\32` and `\34`; undo this to get the 148 byte function.

I computed parts of this hash function with [GPerf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/).

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>348</s>  242 bytes

```perl6
{
  /NI/??9!!chr 32+
  '0A40W00SV0M20LR0O20IJ0LH0WH0YS0H20ID0A50P10IH0F70K10HF0I30LL0JX0JF0HX0LU0LE0JF0AJ0IX0RK0M40XF0QR0PD15Z16016116216316416516616716816916A16B16C16D16E16F16G16H16I16J16K16L16M16N16O1140V313F0XS0FU0N712A12B12C12D12E12F12G12H12I12J12K12L12M12N12O12P12Q12R12S12T12U12V12W12X12Y12Z0ZA0PU11L0AA'
  .comb(3).map({:36($_)}).first(:k,[+] .ords)
} # 348
```

```perl6
{chr 32+"\x95ǐǠŬšƉĘŗȌȴĎĽ\x96ŖŁöģěĈśŊčĂĹŔĸ¤ĦƱŮȃƿƍʶʷʸʹʺʻʼʽʾʿˀˁ˂˃˄˅ˆˇˈˉˊʠʡʢʣʤɝǚʅǥâĿʇʈʉʊʋʌʍʎʏʐʑʒʓʔʕʖʗʘʙʚʛɱɲɳɴɵțųɃ\x9b".ords.first: :k,[+] .ords.map(*%43)}
```

```perl6
{
  chr 32+
  "\x95ǐǠŬšƉĘŗȌȴĎĽ\x96ŖŁöģěĈśŊčĂĹŔĸ¤ĦƱŮȃƿƍʶʷʸʹʺʻʼʽʾʿˀˁ˂˃˄˅ˆˇˈˉˊʠʡʢʣʤɝǚʅǥâĿʇʈʉʊʋʌʍʎʏʐʑʒʓʔʕʖʗʘʙʚʛɱɲɳɴɵțųɃ\x9b"
  .ords.first: :k,[+] .ords.map(*%43)
}
```

usage:

```perl6
my &code = {...}

# testing
my $test = [~] (' '..'~')».uniname».&code;
my $comparison = [~] ' '..'~';
say $test eq $comparison; # True

say code 'HYPHEN-MINUS'; # -
```