# Race of the Digits

Tags: code-golf, simulation

You should write a program or function which given a starting order of distinct one-digit positive integers and the length of the track as input outputs or returns the finish order of the numbers.

The input `[5,1,2,6,7] and 14` defines the following race:

```
--------------
76215 ->
--------------
```

### Rules of the race

- The track wraps around and digits can go multiple laps.
- Order of steps is cyclic and based on the starting position. In our example `5 1 2 6 7 5 1 2 ...`.
- There can be no multiple digits in the same position.
- Every digit has a speed of `digit_value` cell per step. Overtaking a digit or a continuous block of digits costs one extra step. If the digit doesn't have the necessary speed for that it will stop before the (block of) digit(s). Examples:

  ```
  [41   ] => [ 1 4 ]  4 overtakes 1

  [2 1  ] => [ 21  ]  2 can only move 1 as it can't move 3 to overtake 1

  [4 12 ] => [ 412 ]  4 can only move 1 as it can't move 5 to overtake 12     

  [   3 ] => [ 3   ]  3 starting a new lap
  ```
- Every digit has to go `digit_value` laps before it finishes. A lap is completed when the last cell of the track is left. A finished digit is removed from the track.
- *Note that a digit might reach its starting position multiple times through a step and complete multiple laps.*

### Input

- A list of distinct one-digit positive integers (`1..9`) with at least one element and a single positive integer, greater than the length of the list, the length of the track.

### Output

- A list of digits in the order they finished in any unambiguous format.

### Examples

A visual step-by-step example for the input `starting_order = [5,9,2] and length = 6`

```
295   | Start position
29   5| digit 5 moves
2  9 5| digit 9 moves, finishing lap #1
  29 5| digit 2 moves
 529  | digit 5 moves, finishing lap #1
 52  9| digit 9 moves, finishing lap #2
 5  29| digit 2 moves
   529| digit 5 moves
 9 52 | digit 9 moves, finishing laps #3 and #4
29 5  | digit 2 moves, finishing lap #1
29   5| digit 5 moves
2  9 5| digit 9 moves, finishing lap #5
  29 5| digit 2 moves
 529  | digit 5 moves, finishing lap #2
 52  9| digit 9 moves, finishing lap #6
 5  29| digit 2 moves
   529| digit 5 moves
 9 52 | digit 9 moves, finishing laps #7 and #8
 9 5  | digit 2 moves, finishing lap #2 --> remove 2 from the track
59    | digit 5 moves, finishing lap #3
5     | digit 9 moves, finishing lap #9 --> remove 9 from the track
     5| digit 5 moves
    5 | digit 5 moves, finishing lap #4
      | digit 5 moves, finishing lap #5 --> remove 5 from the track
------
Finish order: 2 9 5
```

Examples in format `Input => Output`

```
[3], 2  =>  [3]

[9, 5], 3  =>  [9, 5]

[5, 9, 2], 6  =>  [2, 9, 5]

[5, 9, 2], 10  =>  [5, 9, 2]

[5, 7, 8, 1, 2], 10  =>  [1, 5, 7, 8, 2]

[5, 1, 6, 8, 3, 2], 17  =>  [1, 6, 8, 2, 3, 5]

[1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9], 15  =>  [1, 7, 8, 9, 2, 3]

[9, 8, 7, 3, 2, 1], 15  =>  [8, 7, 9, 1, 2, 3]

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 20  =>  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1], 20  =>  [8, 7, 5, 9, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3]
```

This is code-golf so the shortest entry wins.

Comment: Presumably, the input array cannot have duplicate elements?  It looks that way, but I don't see that condition stated explicitly.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, there can't be any duplicate digits. Edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: For test case #6 (length=17) I get a slightly different result (last two digits reversed). I was wondering where my mistake is. My race log is [this](http://pastebin.com/GFeimS5j). Can you please provide yours so I can diff and find my mistake?

Comment: @w0lf [Log difference here.](https://www.diffchecker.com/txdp2eh0) You skip moving with 6 after 1 finishes where the derivation starts. (Note my log contains the digits before removed from the track and yours don't.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Ruby 229 <s>236</s>

This is a function that takes two parameters: an array representing the digits and an int representing the length of the track. It returns an array, representing the order in which the digits finish the race.

```rb
F=->d,l{
i=0
t=d.map{|x|[x,d.size-(i+=1)]}
r=[]
d.cycle.map{|n|
t==[]&&break
(c=t.find{|x,_|x==n})&&(s=n
w=c[1]
o=p
(a=(t-[c]).map{|_,p|p%l}
s-=1;w+=1
a&[w%l]==[]?(o=p;c[1]=w):o||s-=o=1)while s>0
c[1]>=n*l&&(t.delete c;r<<n))}
r}
```

Test it online: http://ideone.com/KyX5Yu

*Edit:* Figured out some [tricks](https://github.com/clupascu/codegolf/commits/master/49549-race-of-the-digits/race-of-the-digits-golfed.rb) to save some more chars.

Ungolfed version:

```rb
F=->digits,length{
  digit_positions = digits.map.with_index{|d,i|[d,digits.size-i-1] }

  result = []

  digits.cycle.map{|n|
    break if digit_positions==[]
    crt = digit_positions.find{|x,_|x==n}
    next unless crt

    steps_left = n
    pos = crt[1]
    taking_over = false

    while steps_left > 0
      other_pos = (digit_positions-[crt]).map{|_,p|p%length}

      steps_left-=1
      pos += 1

      if other_pos.include? (pos%length)
        steps_left -= 1 unless taking_over
        taking_over = true
      else
        taking_over = false
        crt[1] = pos
      end
    end

    if crt[1] >= n*length
      digit_positions.delete(crt)
      result<<n
    end
  }
  result
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 345 bytes

Too bad it's not shorter than @w0lf's, but whatev. (Note that the large indents are tabs, which translate to 4-space when I post.)

```
def r(o,l):
 n=len(o);s,t,a,d=dict(zip(o,range(n)[::-1])),-1,{_:0 for _ in o},[]     
 while len(s):
    t+=1;g=o[t%n]
    if g in d:continue
    y,k=s[g],1;i=z=w=0
    for _ in[0]*g:
     i+=1;m=y+i;e,p=m%l,m/l
     if-~a[g]+w>=g<d>m>=l:a[g]+=1;del s[g];d+=[g];break
     if e in s.values()and e!=y:i-=k;k=0
     else:k,s[g],(w,z)=1,e,[(w,z),(z,p)][z<p]
    a[g]+=z
 print d
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my magical padded code

### C (<del>457</del> 430b)

```
int v(int*M,int m){
int i,n,c,d,e=32,f=48,u=0,g=10,h,k,r,l=m,j;char a,*b=&a,*B,V[m];
for (i=0;u<m*m*m;i=(++u%m),*B=*b=(u<=l)?*b:e,b=B=&a)
printf("%c%c",0*(V[i]=(u<l?u>=(r=l-sizeof(M)/4)?M[u-r]+f:e:V[i])),((((V[c=(((V[i]=u<l?e:V[i])-f)/10<u/m)?j>=0&h<i|((h=(j=strchr(V+((k=(m+(d=(i-(V[i]-f)%g+1)))%m)),e)-V)<0?(int)(strchr(V,e)-V):(int)j)>=k)*(k>i)?h:m :m])=((V[c]==e)?(*(b=V+i)+(d<0)*g):V[c])))-f)%11==0?(*(B=V+c)-f)%g+f:0);
getch();
}
```

**Note**: it needs more improvement ...

**EDIT:** code shortened ...
- sizeof(int)=4 , function=v , still remains some variable replacing to do .

Comment: My C is rusty, but those calls to `sizeof` seem like they could be replaced by a magic number.  Maybe it wouldn't be as portable, but hey--this is code golf.

Comment: Your code seems to be 453 chars long, not 457. Also, I think you can shorten it further by removing unnecessary whitespace and giving the function a shorter name.

Comment: well thanks for proposals , but the important thing for me , i succeeded to pack the whole thing in two functions , for loop and printf , the only flaw i encoutered , the program keep printing [empty characters](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/49606/38337) instead of nils . but the race still ends properly if we knock away that impotant void betweed digits

Comment: Iirc variables are int by default. So: `v(int*M,int m){e=32;f=48;u=0;l=m;char a,`... Also, almost all of that whitespace is unneccesary; `,V[m];for(i=0;`...`)printf(`...`);getch();}`.