# Leap for Leap Seconds!

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, date

Since today marks the occasion of the 26th [leap second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) ever to occur, your challenge will be to output the date and time of every leap second in GMT or UTC that has occurred so far, as well as the one to occur today.

#### Input

There is no input.

#### Output

```
1972-06-30 23:59:60
1972-12-31 23:59:60
1973-12-31 23:59:60
1974-12-31 23:59:60
1975-12-31 23:59:60
1976-12-31 23:59:60
1977-12-31 23:59:60
1978-12-31 23:59:60
1979-12-31 23:59:60
1981-06-30 23:59:60
1982-06-30 23:59:60
1983-06-30 23:59:60
1985-06-30 23:59:60
1987-12-31 23:59:60
1989-12-31 23:59:60
1990-12-31 23:59:60
1992-06-30 23:59:60
1993-06-30 23:59:60
1994-06-30 23:59:60
1995-12-31 23:59:60
1997-06-30 23:59:60
1998-12-31 23:59:60
2005-12-31 23:59:60
2008-12-31 23:59:60
2012-06-30 23:59:60
2015-06-30 23:59:60
```

#### Rules

Since I doubt there are many built-ins that allow leap-seconds, I'll allow them.

Standard loopholes are disallowed.

Shortest code wins.

Date format must have a zero-padded month and a 4-digit year, as well as military time and a space separating the time from the date. Putting `UTC` at the end is optional. Your choice of dashes or slashes.

EDIT: Yep as predicted, this became an encoding challenge. If only encoding could fix the leap second problem, ...then all our code would be much more practical. Maybe we need some ideas for more fun challenges with practical uses?

Comment: Is the output required to have that exact distribution, or it can have any distribution as long as the 26 dates are there?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel They need to be in this order.

Comment: Off topic, but looking at the list, I'm left wondering why we need fewer leap seconds these days than we did in the previous century.

Comment: @MrLister View the linked Wikipedia article. I think it has to do with Earth's changing rotational speed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## CJam, <s>72</s> <s>70</s> <s>69</s> 64 bytes

```
26,"~g¼K&Béx¸¦­Ø"240bFbf{<1b2md\1972+'-@6X$4*-'-Z3$" 23:59:60"N}
```

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=26%2C%22~g%C2%BCK%26B%C3%A9x%C2%B8%C2%A6%C2%AD%C3%98%22240bFbf%7B%3C1b2md%5C1972%2B'-%406X%244*-'-Z3%24%22%2023%3A59%3A60%22N%7D).

#### Idea

We start by encoding each leap second as **2 * (Y - 1972) + D**, where **D** is **1** if it occurs in December and **0** otherwise.

The array of all encoded leap seconds is:

```
[0 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 18 20 22 26 31 35 37 40 42 44 47 50 53 67 73 80 86]
```

Let's call this array **L**.

Since the array is in ascending order, we can store the consecutive differences instead of the actual numbers:

```
[1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 4 5 4 2 3 2 2 3 3 3 14 6 7 6]
```

Treating this array as the digits of a base 15 number, we obtain the integer

```
19238985373462115979359619336
```

which digits in base 240 (cast to characters) are

```
~g¼K&Béx¸¦­Ø
```

#### Code

```
26,             e# Push I := [0 ... 25].
"~g¼K&Béx¸¦­Ø"   e# Push the string from above.
240bFb          e# Convert from base 250 to base 15 to push L.
f{              e# For each J in I:
                e#   Push L.
  <             e#   Replace L with L[:J].
  1b            e#   Push the sum S of the integers in L[:J].
  2md           e#   Push (S / 2) and (S % 2).
  \1972+        e#   Add 1972 to (S / 2).
  '-@           e#   Push '-' and rotate (S % 2) on top.
  6X$4*-        e#   Compute (6 - 4 * (S % 2)).
  '-Z           e#   Push '-' and 3.
  3$            e#   Push a copy of (S % 2).
  " 23:59:60"   e#   Push that string.
  N             e#   Push a linefeed.
}
```

Comment: That feeling when you have a built in that almost entirely solves the problem and yet the manual solution in CJam is shorter.

Comment: @AlexA. There are some built-ins in Mathematica which I can reimplement in fewer bytes *in Mathematica*.

Comment: @MartinBüttner: Brutal.

Answer (score 35):

## R, <s>78</s> 75 bytes

Built-ins, you say? Well...

```r
message(paste(as.Date(.leap.seconds)-1,"23:59:60\n"),"2015-06-30 23:59:60")
```

R has an automatic variable `.leap.seconds` which contains the date and time of each leap second insertion, given in the system's local time. As of R version 3.2.0, this does not include today, so I've added that manually.

Ungolfed + explanation:

```r
# Convert the datetime values to UTC dates. These will be a day past the
# expected output, so we can subtract 1 to get what we want.
dates <- as.Date(.leap.second) - 1

# Paste the UTC time and a newline onto the end of each date
datetimes <- paste(dates, "23:59:60\n")

# Print each time, including today, on its own line
message(datetimes, "2015-06-30 23:59:60")
```

You can [try it online](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=KmbJDJDY)!

Comment: if you can assign "23:59:60" to a variable, you might save some chars

Comment: @NotthatCharles: I had thought about that, but R's method of combining strings is not concise enough to make constructing today's date and time shorter. Thanks for the input though!

Answer (score 24):

## HTML, 594 bytes

```
1972-06-30 23:59:60<br>1972-12-31 23:59:60<br>1973-12-31 23:59:60<br>1974-12-31 23:59:60<br>1975-12-31 23:59:60<br>1976-12-31 23:59:60<br>1977-12-31 23:59:60<br>1978-12-31 23:59:60<br>1979-12-31 23:59:60<br>1981-06-30 23:59:60<br>1982-06-30 23:59:60<br>1983-06-30 23:59:60<br>1985-06-30 23:59:60<br>1987-12-31 23:59:60<br>1989-12-31 23:59:60<br>1990-12-31 23:59:60<br>1992-06-30 23:59:60<br>1993-06-30 23:59:60<br>1994-06-30 23:59:60<br>1995-12-31 23:59:60<br>1997-06-30 23:59:60<br>1998-12-31 23:59:60<br>2005-12-31 23:59:60<br>2008-12-31 23:59:60<br>2012-06-30 23:59:60<br>2015-06-30 23:59:60
```

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Vioz- This question is tagged [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] and so this is a perfectly legal answer.  Not likely to win though...

Comment: But how about a curl command to extract the answer from this page?

Comment: @mlepage That's one of the "standard loopholes".

Comment: @Voitcus save in file, open in a browser. It's a `working` html code

Comment: @edc65 Just because some browsers make it work, doesn't make it valid. According the W3C validation tool, this is not valid.

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea Yeah, so what? Vailidity is not requested in `code golf` challenges.

Comment: You could replace `<br>` with `\n`. You'll need to view source, but it does save bytes. And the validness depends on which htmlversion you use. There are versions where this is valid

Comment: Technically, you are hardcoding the output which is one of the loopholes!

Comment: @Mhmd basically everybody is hardcoding the output, except the R solution, which uses a built-in function, which some might also consider a loophole.

Comment: According to the META (http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2073/14732), this is not a programming language since it failt on Point 4.

Comment: @PeterOlson: Built-ins in this case were explicitly allowed by the OP. And since this is [tag:kolmogorov-complexity], hard-coding the output is pretty much expected.

Comment: @Voitcus The smallest HTML5 document **that validates**  is `<!DOCTYPE html><title>x</title>`. There is no need for a `<body>`, `<head>` or even an `<html>`.

Comment: [It most definitely *is* HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15458987/497418), just not valid HTML. Also, using the `<pre>` element would have saved some characters.

Comment: @JacobRaihle I see that now after checking the rules. :-)

Comment: -1: "program" size is larger than expected output - this is not fun for [kolmogorov-complexity]

Comment: @anatolyg YOU'RE not fun for [kolmogorov-complexity]

Comment: @Voitcus This is Code Golf not Code Review... The code doesn't need to be valid.

Comment: I still don't understand this answer. Save the question text with normal returns as a plain text file, you can still open it in a browser, _and_ you would save 75 bytes. Anyway, Voitcus has quite some rep in the PHP tag in SO, so I can only assume he knows about optional start tags. Ergo he's trolling.

Comment: @MrLister I was not trolling, I'm sorry if you took me wrong. I am quite new on this site and maybe did not understand something - please excuse me. I have deleted all my comments in this thread.

Comment: Why the hell is this at +23? It's not even funny.

Comment: @ThomasKwa TIL humor is objective

Comment: @VijayRamamurthy You're right, but if the votes for this started at +0/-2 I guarantee you we'd all be piling downvotes on it.

Comment: Yeah, you're right... I too am surprised at the feedback this answer got

Answer (score 11):

## C, <s>160</s> <s>146</s> <s>141</s> 140 bytes

First time posting, not sure what "standard loopholes" are. I have printf warnings of course.

**160 bytes:**

The original idea is to encode leap seconds using two bits per year: one for June and one for December. The encoding is consumed one bit at a time by the inner while loop. Without a 128-bit integer, the outer while loop is necessary. The rest is all bookkeeping and math. :-)

```c
int main(){long long X=0x2495288454AAAB,Y=1972,Z=1;while(Y<2000){while(X){if(X&1)printf("%d-%02d-%d 23:59:60\n",Y,6*(2-Z),31-Z);Y+=Z^=1;X>>=1;}X=0x104082000;}}
```

**141 bytes:**

Applying the suggested tips gets it down to 146 bytes. Then I found a way to simplify the outer while condition (from Y<2000 to just Z), bringing it down to 141 bytes. So close to a tweet!

```c
main(Z){long long X=0x2495288454AAAB,Y=1972;while(Z){while(X)X&1?printf("%d-%02d-%d 23:59:60\n",Y,12-6*Z,31-Z):1,Y+=Z^=1,X/=2;X=4362608640;}}
```

**140 bytes:**

I noticed the dash in the date could be eliminated by making the day negative. Can't do it with the month as well due to leading zero in June. But at least it fits in a tweet now!

```c
main(Z){long long X=0x2495288454AAAB,Y=1972;while(Z){while(X)X&1?printf("%d-%02d%d 23:59:60\n",Y,12-6*Z,Z-31):1,Y+=Z^=1,X/=2;X=4362608640;}}
```

**Pretty version:**

```c
main(Z) {
    long long X = 0x2495288454AAAB, Y = 1972;
    while (Z) {
        while (X)
            X&1 ? printf("%d-%02d%d 23:59:60\n", Y, 12-6*Z, Z-31) : 1,
            Y += Z ^= 1,
            X /= 2;
        X = 4362608640;
    }
}
```

**Bonus version:**

I eliminated the outer loop by bit-shifting one 64-bit integer into another, but it's 150 bytes, due to the rather long "unsigned long long"; if I could use something like "uint64" it would be 138 bytes.

```c
main(Z) {
    unsigned long long Y = 1972, X = 0x2495288454AAAB, W = 8520720;
    while (X)
        X&1 ? printf("%d-%02d-%d 23:59:60\n", Y, 12-6*Z, 31-Z) : 1,
        Y += Z^= 1,
        X = X/2 | (W>>=1)<<63;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. "Standard loopholes" refers [to this post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/8478), but generally it just means "use common sense and don't cheat". :)

Comment: I think using a `for` loop will save some bytes. BTW, `int main()` --> `main()`. You might find [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2203/tips-for-golfing-in-c) very helpful.

Comment: Also: `X>>=1` is the same as `X/=2`, `6*(2-Z)` is the same as `12-6*Z`, and `4362608640` is one byte shorter than `0x104082000`. The `int` in front of `main()` is unnecessary, and if you change `main()` to `main(Z)` then you can remove the declaration `Z=1`.

Comment: Really nice solution- another thing to think about- you can change `if(X&1)printf(...);` with `X&1?printf(...):1;` which saves 1 byte

Comment: and rather than `while(X){...}` use commas so you can remove the braces- `while(X)X&1?printf("%d-%02d-%d 23:59:60\n",Y,6*(2-Z),31-Z):1,Y+=Z^=1,X>>=1;` saving another 2 bytes

Comment: Thanks for all those tips. I wondered about things like ternary and commas but it was late and I was happy just to get it working. I will check out the links.

Comment: on most 64-bit Unix-like systems you can use just `long` instead of `long long`

Answer (score 9):

### Python 3, 91

Uses the encoding and string formatting [by Sp3000](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52462/20260), but stores the values in a [Python 3 bytes object](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51622/20260) rather than a magic number.

```python
for n in b'()+-/1357:<>BGKMPRTWZ]kqx~':print('%d-%02d-3%d 23:59:60'%(1952+n/2,n%2*6+6,n%2))
```

The encoding only needs 86 of the 256 possible values of a bytes, so a range of printable characters is used to make it look nicer.

Answer (score 7):

## Brainfuck, 806

```
++++++++[>++++++>+++++++>+++++++>++++++>++++++>++++++>+++++++>++++++>++++++>++++++>++++>++++++>++++++>+++++++>+++++++>+++++++>+++++++>+++++++>++++++>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<-]>+>+>->++>--->>-->--->+++>>>++>+++>++>--->+>++>-->>++[<]>[.>]<[<]>>>>>>+>---->>>+[<]>[.>]<[<]>>>>+[<]>[.>]<[<]>>>>+[<]>[.>]<[<]>>>>+[<]>[.>]<[<]>>>>+[<]>[.>]<[<]>>>>+[<]>[.>]<[<]>>>>+[<]>[.>]<[<]>>>>+[<]>[.>]<[<]>>>+>-------->>->++++>>>-[<]>[.>]<[<]>>>>+[<]>[.>]<[<]>>>>+[<]>[.>]<[<]>>>>++[<]>[.>]<[<]>>>>++>>+>---->>>+[<]>[.>]<[<]>>>>++[<]>[.>]<[<]>>>+>---------[<]>[.>]<[<]>>>>++>>->++++>>>-[<]>[.>]<[<]>>>>+[<]>[.>]<[<]>>>>+[<]>[.>]<[<]>>>>+>>+>---->>>+[<]>[.>]<[<]>>>>++>>->++++>>>-[<]>[.>]<[<]>>>>+>>+>---->>>+[<]>[.>]<[<]>+>--------->--------->---[<]>[.>]<[<]>>>>+++[<]>[.>]<[<]>>>+>------>>->++++>>>-[<]>[.>]<[<]>>>>+++[<]>[.>]
```

You can [run it on this online interpreter.](http://copy.sh/brainfuck/)

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, <s>111</s> 104 bytes

```py
n=0x6697f252225354422533333330;y=1972
while n:print'%d-%02d-3%d 23:59:60'%(y,n%2*6+6,n%2);y+=n/2%8;n/=16
```

Base encoding and more base encoding.

Answer (score 5):

## GNU sed+date: 112

Common Linux distributions have the leap seconds built-in, too.  Using GNU sed and date:

```
sed -n 's/^\([0-9]\+\).*/1899-12-31 \1sec/p' /usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list|date -f- +"%Y-%m-%d 23:59:60"
```

## GNU sed+date: 90

Safing a few characters by cutting the path:

```
sed -n 's/^\([0-9]\+\).*/1899-12-31 \1sec/p' /u*/s*/z*/leap*|date -f- +'%Y-%m-%d 23:59:60'
```

## GNU sed+date tuned by Toby Speight: 84

Deeply golfed version proposed in the comments:

```
sed -nr 's/^([0-9]+).*/date -d "1899-12-31 \1sec" "+%F 23:59:60"/ep' /u*/s*/z*/leap*
```

Comment: Thanks for teaching me where to find the leap-seconds data.  Unfortunately, my `date` (GNU 8.23) displays those as the first second of the next minute.  What are you using that understands the 60-second minute?

Comment: With GNU coreutils, I got it down to 76, shaving bytes with the `-r` flag, substituting `date` in with the `s///e` modifier, and replacing `%Y-%m-%d` with `%F` in `date`:  TZ=UTC `sed -nr 's/^([0-9]+).*/date -d "1900-1-1 \1sec" "+%F %T"/ep' /u*/s*/z*/leap*`

Comment: I knew I missed something. Seems there is no way around specifying this manually, at least not worse than most of the other solutions do. Let's see if somebody comes up with some date library to fiddle the numbers properly supporting those seconds.

Comment: I got there by using `1899-12-31 \1sec` for the date, and hardcoding `23:59:60` as the time: `sed -nr 's/^([0-9]+).*/date -d "1899-12-31 \1sec" "+%F 23:59:60"/ep' /u*/s*/z*/leap*`

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (*ES6*) 125

The newline inside `` is significant and counted.

To test, run the snippet below (being EcmaScript 6, Firefox only)

```js
alert([..."09:;=DEFIX[01234567?ABGJQS"].map((c,i)=>c.charCodeAt()+1924+(i>10?'-12-31':'-06-30')+' 23:59:60').sort().join`
`)
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 198 bytes

```
foreach([.5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.5,10.5,11.5,13.5,16,18,19,20.5,21.5,22.5,24,25.5,27,34,37,40.5,43.5] as$d){$h=(int)$d-ceil($d);echo date("Y-m-d 23:59:60",mktime(0,0,0,-6*$h,31+$h,(int)$d+1972))."\n";}
```

Unfortunately, I don't know if I can insert `\n` in the date function. If so, this is 3 bytes less because of `.""`.

Comment: You can strip both `(int)` and remove some whitespace. Date throws an error, if the default timezone is not set, silence it with an `@`.
187 bytes:
`foreach([.5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.5,10.5,11.5,13.5,16,18,19,20.5,21.5,22.5,24,25.5,27,34,37,40.5,43.5]as$d){$h=$d-ceil($d);echo@date("Y-m-d 23:59:60",mktime(0,0,0,-6*$h,31+$h,$d+1972))."\n";}`

Answer (score 2):

## 8086 machine code + DOS, 92 bytes

Hexdump of the code:

```
BE 3A 01 B1 57 D1 E0 75 03 AD EB F9 72 09 50 BA
47 01 B4 09 CD 21 58 BB 50 01 81 77 FC 01 04 80
37 01 80 3F 31 74 10 83 EB 05 4B FE 07 80 3F 3A
75 05 C6 07 30 EB F3 E2 CC C3 AA 2A 77 B5 6A DD
DF B6 BE FF 7D BF 31 39 37 32 2D 30 36 2D 33 30
20 32 33 3A 35 39 3A 36 30 0D 0A 24
```

To run, write the 92 bytes into a `com`-file and run under 32-bit Windows or DOSBox.

The code uses a bitmap with 87 bits, one per half a year. The bits are arranged into groups of 16, starting from MSB.

Decoding the bitmap:

```
                 ; when the program starts, ax=0 (tested on DOSBox)
myloop:
    shl ax, 1    ; shift the MSB left into the carry flag
    jnz mywork   ; if some bits are left in the register, work normally
    lodsw        ; if all bits were shifted out, load the next 16 bits
    jmp myloop   ; and check the MSB again
```

Because of the code's structure, some bits are lost during decoding, so I had to repeat them. This repeating doesn't bloat the bitmap because I had to pad 87 bits to 96 bits anyway.

After printing (or not printing) the leap second, the code increases the date by half a year, using manipulations on the ASCII codes of the output message.

Source code (can be assembled with [`tasm`](http://www.phatcode.net/downloads.php?id=280)):

```
    mov si, offset mydata
    mov cl, 57h ; number of iterations

myloop:
    shl ax, 1   ; shift the MSB left into the carry flag
    jnz mywork  ; if some bits are left in the register, work normally
    lodsw       ; if all bits were shifted out, load the next 16 bits
    jmp myloop  ; and check the MSB again
mywork:
    jc myinc_date ; shifted bit 1? - skip printing the message

    push ax
    mov dx, offset mymsg
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h     ; print the message
    pop ax

myinc_date:
    mov bx, offset mymsg + 9 ; pointer to the middle of the message
    xor word ptr [bx - 4], 401h ; change month 06<->12
    xor byte ptr [bx], 1 ; change day 30<->31
    cmp byte ptr [bx], '1'
    je myloop_end ; if 31 December, no need to increase the year
    sub bx, 5 ; pointer beyond the last digit of the year

myinc_year:
    dec bx
    inc byte ptr [bx] ; increase the digit
    cmp byte ptr [bx], '0' + 10
    jne myloop_end ; if the digit was less than 9, done
    mov byte ptr [bx], '0' ; set the digit to 0
    jmp myinc_year ; continue increasing other digits

myloop_end:
    loop myloop
    ret ; terminate the program

; In the following bitmap, the spaces before some LSBs
; show that the least significant 1-bit and all
; following 0-bits are lost during decoding.
mydata:
    dw 02aaah ; 00101010101010     10
    dw 0b577h ; 101101010111011    1
    dw 0dd6ah ; 11011101011010     10
    dw 0b6dfh ; 101101101101111    1
    dw 0ffbeh ; 11111111101111     10
    dw 0bf7dh ; 101111110111110    1

mymsg:
    db '1972-06-30 23:59:60',13,10,'$'
```

Comment: I would like to test this, but I can't seem to find a single editor anywhere that allows you to paste hex and save it to a binary file.

Comment: @MrLister any normal hex editor should do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>123</s> <s>121</s> <s>116</s> <s>114</s> 111

I've managed to get it pretty short, but I'm not sure how much shorter it can get. I tried using `exec`, but the formatting gets to be too costly.

I used a base 16 encoding of the table from the linked Wikipedia page.

Edit: Using hex encoding is shorter than base 36 (see the less golfed version.)

[**Try it here**](http://ideone.com/AGUrW8)

```python
n=0x410208002495288454aaab
for i in range(88):
    if n%2:print"%d-%02d-3%d 23:59:60"%(1972+i/2,i%2*6+6,i%2)
    n/=2
```

Less golfed:

```python
s=bin(int('WELD24ZDGIMBWWLFM',36))[2:]
for i in range(44):
    t,s=int(s[0]),s[1:]
    if t:print"%d-06-30 23:59:60"%(i+1972)
    t,s=int(s[0]),s[1:]
    if t:print"%d-12-31 23:59:60"%(i+1972)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - <strike>88</strike> 84 bytes

Converts to char to compress the data and saves the `06-30` versus `12-31` data as binary number.

```
jbm++-2047ed?"-06-30"hd"-12-31"" 23:59:60"C,j33678243 2CM"KKJIHGFEDBA@><:9765421*'#
```

(there is a space there at the end)

[Try it here online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jbm%2B%2B-2047ed%3F%22-06-30%22hd%22-12-31%22%22+23%3A59%3A60%22C%2Cj33678243+2CM%22KKJIHGFEDBA%40%3E%3C%3A9765421*%27%23+&debug=1).

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <strike>204</strike> 201

```python
e,g,h=0,1972,0
for i in range(1,27):e,g,h={2:1,9:2,10:1,12:2,15:1,16:2,17:1,20:2,21:1,22:7,23:3,24:4,25:3}.get(i,e),g+e,(h,1-h)[i in[2,10,14,17,20,21,22,25]];print`g`+("-06-30","-12-31")[h]+" 23:59:60"
```

You can play with it on [repl.it](https://repl.it/utN).

Edit: Thoroughly beaten! The compression answers are amazingly short.

Comment: Surprisingly, my [PHP anwser](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52474/41819) is shorter, using similar algorithm. I've always expected Python be more compact. Maybe you could golf it a little more?

Comment: I'll take a look.  I think the best route is compression though, and others have already done that

Answer (score 1):

## q/kdb+, <s>95</s> <s>94</s> 93 bytes

```
asc 1_" "0:([]raze("DEFGHIJKSUV[^eh";"DMNOQXYZ]lo"){("d"$"m"$-12*95-6h$x)-y}'1 185;`23:59:60)
```

**Explanation**

For each year **+ 1**, encode for years since 1905 as an ASCII character, e.g.:

```
1972 -> 1973 -> 68 -> D
```

`6h$x` turns `"D"` back to `68`. Since `q`'s date epoch is `2000.01.01`, we subtract `95` and perform the integers-to-date conversion `"d"$"m"$-12*95-6h$x`.

The reason we **+ 1** above is to subtract the number of days from the start of **next year** to get the *actual year's* 31st December or 30th June, namely 1 or 185 days. Therefore, `"DEFGHIJKSUV[^eh"` represents the years with a leap second in December, and `"DMNOQXYZ]lo"` for those in June. The pairing-subtraction is done via `(a;b){x-y}'(c;d)`, where `a` and `b` are years that will be subtracted by `c` and `d` number of days respectively.

`" "0:([]...)` prepares the results to give us the correct formatting, with a small caveat that a column header will be generated. `1_` drops that header and finally apply `asc` to get the ordering correct.

**edit**: 're-base' to subtracting 95 years instead of 100 (saving 1 character).

**edit 2**: re-ordering the operands' positioning inside the integers-to-date conversion function.

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>155</s> <s>149</s> 147 bytes

Here's another approach in C, using strings and run length encoding. Not quite as terse as my other C solution, but maybe it can be improved?

**155 bytes:**

Using a string to hold the month/day.

```c
main(Y){Y=1972;char*M="06-3012-31",*B="#@DGCDF7D3daTdS#!",b,c;while(b=*B++-33){c=b>>1&7;while(c--)printf("%d-%.5s 23:59:60\n",Y++,M+b%2*5);Y+=(b>>4&7)-1;}}
```

**149 bytes:**

Eliminating the month/day string.

```c
main(Y){Y=1972;char*B="#@DGCDF7D3daTdS#!",b,c;while(b=*B++-33){c=b>>1&7;while(c--)printf("%d-%02d-%d 23:59:60\n",Y++,6+b%2*6,30+b%2);Y+=(b>>4&7)-1;}}
```

**147 bytes:**

Eliminating the year initialization.

```c
main(Y){char*B="#@DGCDF7D3daTdS#!",b,c;while(b=*B++-33){c=b>>1&7;while(c--)printf("%d-%02d-%d 23:59:60\n",1971+Y++,6+b%2*6,30+b%2);Y+=(b>>4&7)-1;}}
```

**144 bytes:**

If I reencoded the buffer to make the skip count apply before (not after) the run, then I could reorder the statements in the outer while loop, use the comma operator, and eliminate the braces, saving 2 bytes.

I can save another byte by making the day negative (as in my other solution).

**Pretty:**

```c
main(Y) {
    char *B = "#@DGCDF7D3daTdS#!", // buffer of bytes encoding runs
         b, // current byte
         c; // current count
    while (b = *B++-33) { // get byte
        c = b>>1&7; // get count
        while (c--) printf("%d-%02d-%d 23:59:60\n", 1971+Y++, 6+b%2*6, 30+b%2); // run
        Y += (b>>4&7)-1; // skip years
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

Runs are encoded in bytes. Each byte has one bit to say whether it's June or December, 3 bits for a length count, 3 bits for a skip count, and 1 unused high bit.

The skip count is the number of years to skip after a run; it's offset by -1 to allow for two leap seconds in 1972. The length is how many years in a run; it probably could be offset by +1 but it isn't currently.

So a byte means: "Do LENGTH years of JUNE (or DECEMBER) years of leap seconds, then skip SKIP-1 years" before moving to the next byte.

The bytes are offset by 33 to make them readable and avoid fancy encoding.

This means although we have enough skip bits to cover 1998-2005, we're out of ASCII range, so we have an extra zero length run. Also, 1979 appears on its own because the length 1972-1979 is one too long.

There's enough bits in the bytes, so those issues might be fixable ultimately.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 164 bytes

```
foreach([.5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.5,10.5,11.5,13.5,16,18,19,20.5,21.5,22.5,24,25.5,27,34,37,40.5,43.5]as$d){echo(ceil($d)+1971).($d%2?'-12-31':'-06-30')." 23:59:60\n";}
```

This is just a few modification on @Voitcus's idea

Answer (score 0):

## Python, <strike>221</strike> 217

```python
def d(x):
 q=x%10
 if x%2==0:
  p,r=q/2,"06-30"
 else:
  p,r=(q-1)/2,"12-31"
 return"%d%d-%s 23:59:60"%(p+197,x/10,r)
for x in [20,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91,12,22,32,52,73,93,5,24,34,44,55,74,85,57,87,28,58]:print(d(x))
```

## Some Insights

Basically, `d(x)` decompresses a vector of 3 integers from a single 2-digit integer. `d(x)` is constructed as the inverse function (over the 26 leap seconds datetimes) of `c(v)`, which in turn is a compression function that turns a 3-uple such as (1998,12,31) into a number like 85. To derive the list [20,21...28,58] I designed another algorithm to verify that the compression function is bijective over the domain. That is, I made sure that the following program doesn't produce duplicates, and I used its output as the list of the program above.

```python
dates = [(1972,06,30),
    (1972,12,31),
    (1973,12,31),
    (1974,12,31),
    (1975,12,31),
    (1976,12,31),
    (1977,12,31),
    (1978,12,31),
    (1979,12,31),
    (1981,06,30),
    (1982,06,30),
    (1983,06,30),
    (1985,06,30),
    (1987,12,31),
    (1989,12,31),
    (1990,12,31),
    (1992,06,30),
    (1993,06,30),
    (1994,06,30),
    (1995,12,31),
    (1997,06,30),
    (1998,12,31),
    (2005,12,31),
    (2008,12,31),
    (2012,06,30),
    (2015,06,30)]

def c(v):
    x = (v[0] % 10) * 10
    x += v[2] % 30
    x += 2 * (int(v[0] / 10) - 197)
    return x

for v in dates:
    print(c(v))
```

The compression function `c(v)` was designed to be bijective by using a very simple scheme. Let's take as an example (1998,12,31).

- The expression (v[0] % 10) * 10 selects the units of the year (e.g. 1 9 9 **8** --> 8) and makes it the tenths digit of the output (now x=80).
- There are only two month-day combination in which the leap second thing happens, so I decided to use the day component to distinguish between the 06,30 case and the 12,31 case. The expression v[2] % 30 is 0 if the day is 30, and is 1 if the day is 31. In our example, we add 1 to x (hence, now x=81).
- Finally, I observed that this puzzle involves only 5 decades; hence if I map the first decade (the seventies) to 0 and the last decade (the 2010s) to 4 I can do cool stuff. More specifically, if instead of mapping to 0,1,2,3,4 I map to 0,2,4,6,8 I can add this value to the units of x, which due to the previous rule is either 0 or 1. So in the end we have that also this last step doesn't screw the bijection, and we get that the units of a 06,30 case are one of 0,2,4,6,8 and that the units of a 12,31 case are one of 1,3,5,7,9. Hence the bijection is obvious. In our example, 1998 is in the third decade (70s->0, 80s->1, 90s->2) so we add 2*2=4. So we get x=85.

I wrote the program to verify that this is true, and then I defined `d(x)` as the inverse of `c(v)`. In our example, c((1998,12,31)) is 85 and d(85) correctly prints `1998-12-31 23:59:60`.

Comment: Remove `q=x%10` and replace `q` with `x%10` everywhere. It's shorter. I also give a helpful description of some additional golfing on your program [**here**](http://repl.it/vCQ). I recommend viewing the [Tips for Golfing in Python](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python?s=1|1.1079) page.

Comment: This is *code-golf*, so you should try to shorten the length of your code in any way possible.

Answer (score -1):

**gzip, 114 bytes**

Hexdump:

1f8b080853f9975502006c006dd04b0a80300c84e1bde01dbc40218fa6697aff8309e2a6fa6f3f86cc10adb426a3b95ce62b6a0d398f07d59aeb8e4ed80983701026e1242cc0a9307e1aa11306615211b59710527b3961270cba9994fc7fc944829092faeedc313e7803993cfafb20020000

Create a file with the bytes described above.

Extract using gunzip or another decompression program to get a new file named "l". This file contains the desired output.