# Reverse-Engineer the N-Bonacci sequence[s]

Tags: code-golf, sequence, fibonacci, subsequence

**EDIT: I will be accepting an answer Monday, 2/15/2016. May the bytes be ever in your favor!**

In his ["Print the N-Bonacci Sequence" challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/70476/print-the-n-bonacci-sequence?noredirect=1#comment172535_70476), @DJMcGoathem describes the N-bonacci sequences, wherein the previous *N* numbers are summed, instead of the traditional 2 of the Fibonacci sequence (said to be the "*duo*nacci sequence"). He then asked to take two inputs, X and N, then output the *X*th *N*-nacci number.

I propose the opposite.
Given a sequence, output which *N*-nacci sequence it is a subset of. I say "subset of" because:

- A) these sequences are infinite
- B) if given the start of the sequence, you could just count the number of leading 1s

**In the case that it could belong to multiple *N*-nacci sequences, chose the lowest one.**
**In the case that it does not belong to any *N-nacci* sequence, then your program may do anything other than print something that could be mistaken for output.** These behaviors include (but are not limited to): infinite loop, error, crash, delete itself (*cough cough* [vigil](https://github.com/munificent/vigil) *cough cough*), or create a black hole (as long as this black hole does not produce anything that could be mistaken for valid output).
**For the sake of this challenge, these sequences start with 1.** This means any *N*-nacci sequence starts with *N* ones. Furthermore, *N* must be a positive integer. So no **-1**-nacci, etc.

Test cases:

```
1,1,1 -> 1
49, 97 -> 7
55, 89, 144 -> 2
1 -> 1
6765 -> 2
12, 23, 45, 89 -> 12
100, 199 -> 100
```

Comment: `create a black hole (as long as this black hole does not produce anything that could be mistaken for valid output).` My, the spirals of the black hole are converging to the golden ratio! It _must_ be valid output for a duoacci sequence!

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ It may be a beautiful golden ratio, but Do NOT go near the black hole! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTUQyEr-sg0

Comment: Oh my, this is much harder than I originally thought...

Comment: @mbomb007 what's the difference between positive integers and natural numbers?

Comment: @NotthatCharles Positive integers is a clearer way to say it if you're excluding zero, because natural numbers includes zero.

Comment: @mbomb007 ah.  I thought 1 was the first natural number.  I must have been thinking of counting numbers

Comment: @NotthatCharles It's actually somewhat ambiguous, but I include zero. [See wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Ruby, 94

I'm quite surprised how far I've been able to golf this within the same algorithm!  I started with over 200!

```ruby
->a{1.step.find{|s|x=[1]*(s+z=a.size)
x<<x[-s,s].inject(:+)while x.max<a.max&&s>1
x[-z,z]==a}}
```

Ungolfed:

```ruby
l=->a{
    # ooh! a built-in infinite incrementer!
    1.step.find{|s|
        # if n == 1, z is important, otherwise s.
        x=[1]*(s+z=a.size)
        ## add the next nacci number until we hit or overshot max. 
        ## if s == 1, we don't increment, so don't bother
        x<<x[-s,s].inject(:+)while x.max<g&&s>1
        # eval to true if there's a match, false if not
        x[-z,z]==a
    }
}
```

Comment: How does `x=[1]*(s+z=a.size)` work exactly?

Comment: @Cyoce If `n == 1`, then we will never increment, so we need an array of 1's however long the input is.  If `n > 1`, then we need at least `n` 1's for the sequence.  So `s+a.size` covers `n == 1` for any length of `a`, and it covers the beginning of any other sequence so we can just start adding `s` digits off the batt.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Cyoce and if you're asking a different question, in Ruby, `[1]*number` gives an array of 1's with length `number`.  So `x=[1]*(s+z=a.size)` assigns `a.size` to `z`, then assigns to `x` an array of 1's length `s+z`.

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 46 bytes

```
{∧/0<⍵:⊃⊃⍸A⍷↑{⍵((+/↑),⊢)⍣{</+/¨A⍵}⍵⍴1}¨⍳⊃A←⌽⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pRx3J9A5tHvVutHnU1g1DvDsdHvdsftU2sBgpqaGjrA5maOo@6Fmk@6l1cbaOvrX9oBVDF1logftS7xbD20IpHvZuBOh0ftU141LMXJPU/DcTu7QObtwao6tB6Y6Axj/qmBgc5A8kQD8/g/2kKQBZQnaECEHLBeCaWCpbmcJ6pqYKFpYKhiQlc5FFXkyEyx8TQAsE3NFIwMlYwAWlCiBkYKBhaIvimCiYKxnCegQIQckHY6grqcHGggxUOrTcCYkOELAA)

Anonymous prefix function, taking a vector of integers.

#### How?

```
∧/0<⍵:   ⍝ If the given sequence contains any non-positive integers, then return nothing. Otherwise...
A←⌽⍵     ⍝ Set A to be the reverse of the given sequence
{...}¨⍳⊃ ⍝ For each n in 1 to last element of given sequence, we generate the n-bonacci sequence in reverse order:
 ⍵⍴1       ⍝ Initialize a vector of n 1s (first n terms of the n-bonacci sequence)
 ⍣         ⍝ Do:
 ⍵((+/↑),⊢)  ⍝ Prepend the sum of the most-recent (first) n elements of the vector to the rest of the vector
           ⍝ While
 {</+/¨A⍵}   ⍝ the sum of the n-bonacci sequence generated so far is less than the sum of A
               ⍝ (this doesn't terminate prematurely because:
               ⍝   For n=1, this produces k+2 1s if A consists of k 1s
               ⍝     Otherwise, worst-case is that A has 1 element
               ⍝   For n=2, F_0+F_1+F_2 ... + F_{k-2} = F_k (identity)
               ⍝     F_0 + ... F_{k-1} > F_k, and APL terminates the ⍣-loop in the next step,
               ⍝     after F_k generated
               ⍝   For n>2, F_0+F_1+F_2 ... + F_{k-2} < F_k, so an excess of terms are generated
               ⍝ )
↑        ⍝ Mix to form a matrix, where the n-th row is the n-bonacci sequence
⍸A⍷      ⍝ Find the (row, column) positions of A in the matrix
⊃⊃       ⍝ Take the row of the first one (which would have minimum n)
```

Comment: This really should have gotten a 200-rep bounty, but I made a mistake and only put 100 on it. I'll create a 100-rep bounty for one of your other answers.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 176 bytes

```
def r(n,x):i,f=n,[1]*n;exec"f+=sum(f[i-n:]),;i+=1;"*(x-n);return f
l=input()
m=max(l)+len(l)
for i in range(1,m):
 if any(l==r(i,m)[b:b+len(l)]for b in range(m)):print i;break;
```

Note that this requires input in this format:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3...]
```

rather than

```
1, 1, 2, 3...
```

Fairly straightforward solution, just to get things rolling. I'll work more on golfing it down once somebody else answers. This uses a slightly modified version of the N-Bonnaci generator from [@Data's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70482/31716), so props to him. Then for each N-Bonnaci in range of the input, checks if the input is a subsequence of it.

Comment: try the same suggestions I gave to him: change `f.append` for `f+=`

Comment: @Cyoce oh duh. I'm can't believe I missed something that basic. *fp*

Comment: Is the trailing `;` necessary?

Answer (score 2):

## Lua, <s>324</s> 323 Bytes

When I see other submission, I feel like there's something wrong with my code... But then, I remember that's Lua, and there's isn't all these fancy functionnalities :'(

It was a lot of fun, took me some time actually.

**Edit: Saved 1 byte with a simple trick: using a `::label::`+`goto label` instead a infinite loop done with `while''`.**

```lua
function f(l)c=2 y,z=table.remove,os.exit while(l[1]<2)do y(l,1)if(#l<1)then print(1)z()end end ::q:: a={}for i=1,c do a[i]=1 end b={}for i=1,#l do b[i]=l[i]end while(a[#a]<b[1])do x=0 for i=(#a-c+1>0 and #a-c+1 or 1),#a do x=x+a[i]end a[#a+1]=x if a[#a]==b[1]then y(b,1)end if #b<1 then print(c)z()end end c=c+1 goto q end
```

#### Ungolfed and Explanations

Lua has no way to define a set, subset, or even check if an array/table contains a value without using its index/key. That's why i've decided to remove elements from the array I take as a parameter. that's how I keep record of which elements has already been computed, and if it matched.

```lua
  function f(l)
  c=2
  y,z=table.remove,os.exit           -- Create pointers on table.remove and os.exit
                                     -- saves a total of 9 bytes
  while(l[1]<2)                      -- loop used to remove leading 1
  do 
    y(l,1)
    if(#l<1)                         -- we also check if it was a 1-only array
    then 
      print(1)                       -- if so, we print 1 and exit
      z()
    end 
  end

  ::q::                              -- label q, start of the infinite loop
    a={}for i=1,c do a[i]=1 end      -- fill an array with c 1s
    b={}for i=1,#l do b[i]=l[i]end   -- copy the sequence array
    while(a[#a]<b[1])                -- while max(a)<min(b)
    do
      x=0 for i=(#a-c+1>0            -- iterate from index a.length-c to
                    and #a-c+1       -- to a.length
                    or 1),#a 
      do 
        x=x+a[i]                     -- summing a's elements
      end
      a[#a+1]=x                      -- append x to a
      if a[#a]==b[1]then y(b,1)end   -- if x is equal ot a member of the sequence
                                     -- remove it
      if #b<1 then print(c)z()end    -- if b is empty, it means the subset is in a
                                     -- we print c and exit
    end                              -- else we loop again
    c=c+1                            -- with c+1
  goto q                             -- return to the start of this block
end
```

You can try [Lua online](http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo), and you can copy/paste the following code sample to run some tests. As this function exit when it founds the answer (infinite loop otherwise), you will have to change the index of `test[]` used (don't forget lua is 1-indexed :)).

```lua
function f(l)c=2 y,z=table.remove,os.exit while(l[1]<2)do y(l,1)if(#l<1)then print(1)z()end end ::q:: a={}for i=1,c do a[i]=1 end b={}for i=1,#l do b[i]=l[i]end while(a[#a]<b[1])do x=0 for i=(#a-c+1>0 and #a-c+1 or 1),#a do x=x+a[i]end a[#a+1]=x if a[#a]==b[1]then y(b,1)end if #b<1 then print(c)z()end end c=c+1 goto q end

test={{1,1,1},
{49, 97},
{55, 89, 144},
{1},
{6765},
{12, 23, 45, 89},
{100, 199}}

print(f(test[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 71 bytes

```
(n=1;While[!SubsetQ[LinearRecurrence[s=1~Table~n,s,Max@l],l=#],n++];n)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYy9CoMwFEb3PkVKobR4B2OjNkjAB2ihf9AhOES5aCBm0AiFUl89lS4lfNs5nK9XrsNeOd0o34rrpNGVfmcFLZ6dNijX96ke0V3lSVtUww2baRjQNihHQeeHqg3OFkY4q1dpKjBiU4GNoqqw@62/DNo6UrbyTWHZp1r9CePA84CkKZAjB0IZC3jYZXmWhjoBkhyAsF8eqjhe7vgCvf8C)