# How-many-bonacci-like is this sequence?

Tags: code-golf, sequence, integer, fibonacci

Inspired by @emanresu A's [*Is it a fibonacci-like sequence?*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/242935/9288) Make sure to upvote that challenge as well!

We say a sequence is Fibonacci-like, if, starting from the third term (\$1\$-indexed), each term is the sum of the previous two terms. For example, \$3, 4, 7, 11, 18, 29, 47, 76, 123, 199\cdots\$ is a Fibonacci-like sequence that starts with \$3, 4\$.

Similarly, for any positive integer \$n\$, we say a sequence is \$n\$-bonacci-like, if, starting from the \$n+1\$ term (\$1\$-indexed), each term is the sum of the previous \$n\$ terms. For example, \$2, 4, 5, 11, 20, 36, 67, 123, 226, 416\cdots\$ is a \$3\$-bonacci-like sequence that starts with \$2, 4, 5\$, while \$1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 22, 43, 84, 164, 321\cdots\$ is a \$5\$-bonacci-like sequence that starts with \$1, 2, 4, 7, 8\$.

In particular, constant sequences (sequences where every item are the same) are \$1\$-bonacci-like.

### Task

Given a non-empty list of positive integers, output the smallest \$n\$ such that it could be part of some \$n\$-bonacci-like sequence. You may assume that the input is (non-strictly) increasing.

Note that a list with length \$n\$ is always a part of some \$n\$-bonacci-like sequence.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

### Testcases

```
[3] -> 1
[2, 2, 2] -> 1
[1, 2, 2] -> 3
[2, 3, 4, 7] -> 4
[1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 18] -> 2
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6] -> 6
[2, 4, 5, 11, 20, 36, 67, 123, 226, 416] -> 3
[1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 22, 43, 84, 164, 321] -> 5
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] -> 10
```

Comment: Suggested test cases: `[1, 2, 2] -> 3`, `[2, 3, 4, 7] -> 4`.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/70652/9288).

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>91</s> <s>78</s> 77 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to Giuseppe*

```r
function(x){while(any((rowSums(matrix(c(0,x),sum(x|1),T))-x)[0:-T]))T=T+1;+T}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDRisIwEEXf/YqALxlMIZPUbHel@xObN/GhFsXCNoVqaWT127tTakSjEAIz9547k7SD2zauKMsqH/adK09V47iHv/5Q/e544c6ct03/09VHXhentvK85FJ4EMeu5v6CICxA4mEtvxK7AbC5XeBqYa/3XAI0AJuz5Jvh7KGrBBvPWw2fNR1xWrBUsI8gpxF6kwVDKjALNhXZomOCz0TTKGs5ZSlJ4YasY7aiMUpRlaJ5u@j0iGmTbPRSQUxGHTR0aYWBW75yOgw2IeCTOHn/Ljkb/gE)

Comment: Use `0:-T` to save a byte. The offset with `c(0,x)` to index exactly once and avoid any of the usual matrix exceptions with `[...,drop=T]` is quite clever!

Comment: @Giuseppe - Thanks!

Comment: just curious about something: why don't I see R solutions using the shorter `\(x)...` syntax for functions? EDIT: I don't think TIO supports the new syntax

Comment: @ChechyLevas - your EDIT is correct.  If the only gain is by saving 7 bytes (```function``` > ```\```) it seems boring, and not worth the annoyance of losing TIO support (although you can still use rdrr.io).  Here there's only one function definition so I didn't bother...  Sometimes, though, it can make a non-trivial difference: for instance, it can encourage approaches with more-than-one function definition, that could be prohibitively long with R v≤4.0, but golfy in R ≥v4.1.

Comment: The issue is TIO not being updated, not anything wrong with R. https://github.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline There was a meta post about it, can't find it now. I personally use a local copy of R.

Answer (score 7):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>14</s> <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
?lṠṪ?nȯ⁼)ṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiP2zhuaDhuao/bsiv4oG8KeG5hSIsIiIsIlszXVxuWzIsIDIsIDJdXG5bMSwgMiwgMl1cblsyLCAzLCA0LCA3XVxuWzEsIDMsIDQsIDcsIDExLCAxOF1cblsxLCAxLCAxLCAxLCAxLCAxLCA2XVxuWzIsIDQsIDUsIDExLCAyMCwgMzYsIDY3LCAxMjMsIDIyNiwgNDE2XVxuWzEsIDIsIDQsIDcsIDgsIDIyLCA0MywgODQsIDE2NCwgMzIxXVxuWzEsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDUsIDYsIDcsIDgsIDksIDEwXSJd)

Man this new "lambda to newline" thing is cool.

*-2 thanks to @emanresuA*

### Explained

```
?lṠṪ?nȯ⁼)ṅ
        )ṅ   # Get the first positive integer n where:
  Ṡ          #   the sums of all
?l           #   overlapping windows of the input of length n
   Ṫ         #   with the tail removed
       ⁼     #   exactly equals
    ?nȯ      #   input[n:]
```

Comment: [10](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiP2zhuaDhuao/bsiv4oG8KeG5hSIsIiIsIlszXVxuWzIsIDIsIDJdXG5bMSwgMiwgMl1cblsyLCAzLCA0LCA3XVxuWzEsIDMsIDQsIDcsIDExLCAxOF1cblsxLCAxLCAxLCAxLCAxLCAxLCA2XVxuWzIsIDQsIDUsIDExLCAyMCwgMzYsIDY3LCAxMjMsIDIyNiwgNDE2XVxuWzEsIDIsIDQsIDcsIDgsIDIyLCA0MywgODQsIDE2NCwgMzIxXVxuWzEsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDUsIDYsIDcsIDgsIDksIDEwXSJd)

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 25 bytes

```
f"G1@&l2&Y+3L)G@QJh)=A?@.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3BCsIwEETv@YrBQ6EYarKpsR6kFYSCiCB40JaAXkSh3nro38cNTSkIS7Kz@2b2@@w7/8AHfXNGiSGDg38tal0lHSX3pTmldXU5vtPdvqwy7xxuBzQDrs63xkG0JBEqtHpu@TcSucQmLqKS0Cx0Ead/ZaOVyfVIkmKr5U1wEocQscq1ne@NsUVYsWCk4Im2/BjSM2amWDvxW8YUA2qlhBA/)

Generalization of the convolution method from my [fibonacci-like sequence answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243026/8774).

---

*Previous*

#### [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 30 bytes

```
f"Gn@XH-t:"G@@H+&:)J&)s=-]~?@.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY0/C8IwEMX3fIpHh0KxrflTYy1IMwgtDk4O0hLQRRDUxQ6d/OrxQlMKwpHcu/u9d6/b8HRXPDB0J9QYc1i4e9S8zaXNhipqjGlXcZUc4@Szz@y3NrmzFpcDuhFn63plwXqZwpdvxdLSr1IUKbZhEVQKQUKUYfpXOliJ3Eyk5GTVtPFOSSFSkiqEXu5NsaVfkSCkpInQ9CgpFkzNsXrmd4RxAviaM8Z@)

Answer (score 5):

## Python3, 102 bytes:

```
lambda x,c=0:(v(x,c)and c)or(x and f(x,c+1))
v=lambda x,i:len(x)<=i or(sum(x[:i])==x[i]and v(x[1:],i))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDdboQgEIWv61NMvFnI0o2g61pT@gh9Adc0uIspiX8Ra@zT24ENe9GEEGbOd84A0@/yPQ5pMc17K697p/rmrmBjN5mUZCV4oGq4w42OM9nAHVvXPHJKo1U@cVN2eiAbfZcGkLQ/Pdmq0tRUyq0ytfNhWMXLmhlKdyvjOI6qtIbXD@BRJRi4FUrOIGWQMbgw4FjwwivCK/9W7qXcZ6Dj/HCIBCNyVF2CwDAhsMr4g059kAgjCidjgViBHZ7jlgru0XNA0xCfB88bosnjykmgRMh/Oi6@k0XuwaafxnkBZZeoHWcwYAZoTbfomXyOg2ZgT3bqzEIO1@FAaRm9KNaAhF5NBE0nlPSsui@9qo6BCbAbgDjS1mrMb4nCf2/2Pw)

Answer (score 5):

## [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>15</s> 13 bytes

-2 thanks to @FrownyFrog. (Since the input is non-decreasing, `⍋` can be used instead of `⍳∘≢` to save 2 bytes.)

```
⊃∘⍸⍋(⊃↓⍷+/)¨⊂
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RUw7CsJAEO09xSsVDWZm1nE9TohEhIBCKluFIJGAYOMRvIHWHmUuEneXgLzizfvMK451tj0V9WGXlXXRNPtyGCpr79Zd7Pq0/mP9bRpF@7D@PV/Ovi/rzqGDhUwqcERgGpkhcFgnJ10gAvmk/9DUdFjFlHOIQkOTBcwKRzouxn8fPDiBdyB1EKYxlDSgqbIB5T8)

Taking the sequence `1 1 2 3 5` as an example:

```
   ⍋(     )¨⊂  For each n from 1 to the length of the sequence,  1           2        ...
      ↓        is the sequence with the first n terms removed    1 2 3 5     2 3 5    ...
       ⍷       a subsequence of
        +/     the sums of each n-sized window in the sequence   1 1 2 3 5   2 3 5 8  ...
     ⊃         at the first position?                            no          yes      ...
⊃∘⍸            What is the first index where this is true?       2
```

Comment: I independently came up with a similar solution, but mine is 17 bytes because I'm silly :P `⊃∘⍸⍳∘≢(⊃⊢⍷↑,+⌿)¨⊂`

Comment: use grade instead of ⍳∘≢

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>65</s>  64 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @tsh*

```javascript
f=(a,w)=>a.every((v,i)=>s=i<w|s==v&&s+v-~~a[i-w],s=0)?w:f(a,-~w)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZDRCsIgFIbvewqvhpJbU5utyHqQ4YWsLRbRYoYSxF59nRHrYmwQiQi/@J3/w4txxuZNdX@Et/pUdF2psKGeqIOJClc0T4wdrSBaVe39yyrlgsAuXdi2JqtCr6lVMTn6XQlY2HrS5fXN1tciutZnXOJMaPTLIgStVogtRjSnqN/6P5pRJChaU7ShiEFgqZ6n@QQ92lLP0nLCHIqTTzGPwUTCgF6EgxPnkNZM6g8tJrr5YJ72zyEAlsINk3AIzvS3O5mmxWAghzFboGM9/rW4ewM)

Comment: `f=(a,w)=>a.every((v,i)=>s=i<w|s==v&&s+v-~~a[i-w],s=0)?w:f(a,-~w)`

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `lists.lazy math.unicode`, 68 bytes

```
[ 1 lfrom [ dupd clump [ Σ ] map 1 head* tail? ] with lfilter car ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZG9TsMwFIX3PMVhRSKKf2oCSDAiFhbEVHWwErexcBLjOEKlytPwPrxScBwUOlDEvZOvv3PusbyVhW/d@Pz08Hh/DaM736VGvu/xolyjDHau7a1udqilr9K@0UVbKnTqtVdNobpZAeuU93vrdONxkySHBKEOYBjwV53h4hbkG6axh//BJHhzXIIQkPwXUYTpAv@0OAWLJQbHavKlGZiACDsoA6UCnEziCLPFmcYYeQDAGXIOIjgYJfOaCK@OYBbdRZRcgWTHaeYHZsmQjOsAm61ra6xR9rZEYfrahsPnBzbhK2y4r5Qsz@GlNndh9qZ9FSTaeOVQSIfNOGHp@AU)

### Explanation

Find the first positive integer whose sums of clumps of the input, sans the last element, is the tail end of the input.

`1 lfrom [ ... ] with lfilter car` Find the first positive integer where...

```
           ! { 2 4 5 11 20 36 67 123 226 416 } 3      (for example)
dupd       ! { 2 4 5 11 20 36 67 123 226 416 } { 2 4 5 11 20 36 67 123 226 416 } 3
clump      ! { 2 4 5 11 20 36 67 123 226 416 } {
                 { 2 4 5 }
                 { 4 5 11 }
                 { 5 11 20 }
                 { 11 20 36 }
                 { 20 36 67 }
                 { 36 67 123 }
                 { 67 123 226 }
                 { 123 226 416 }
             }
[ Σ ] map  ! { 2 4 5 11 20 36 67 123 226 416 } { 11 20 36 67 123 226 416 765 }
1 head*    ! { 2 4 5 11 20 36 67 123 226 416 } { 11 20 36 67 123 226 416 }
tail?      ! t
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 76 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,i=1:i*all(E==sum(n[I:I+i])for I,E in enumerate(n[i:]))or f(n,i+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYyxDsIgFEV3v4IR7BukaG1IGDvwDU0HjBBJ4JUgHfx6JHFQm7vdc89Nr/JYUYwp1@pUMPF2NwTBKy790YRAJ6WeW6Q4a6k7vzC3ZqJhIh6JxS3abIpt1MuFsYYcbXLHWU3ZY6GOzj20NHj4ac5wAc6hP4EY/hCHb4adJJp23a0/1/UN)

This is a recursive function that increments `i` until the conditions are met with that `i`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>59</s> 58 bytes

```ruby
->l{1.step.find{|a|l.each_cons(a+1).all?{|*h,g|g==h.sum}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDdasIwFL7vU@RSXYw9Sc06sA58gT1ADCNqa4VYi52D2fTZ62lqYAiHwPd7klxvu7@@yPr52rbAmp@8ZsWpOrTOOMtysy@/95eqmZg3mDJj7WfrZiU9umOWlay5nbuu61erzdeG2VOVN@xs6tZZVxN1z/JfYydWLbaKzbZ6oae0UHetu0gJTeZrApHilAwTIPyDwquCkoSSd88k3vBkKAEEkHqFe@VlpJekr8HEckzwGCskqkMDxzLOESUgw9LxDuOKdJARoC1FBiQegoO3LoNVhHoZMh9ojcc3xRH@Tf8A)

#### Let's check:

This exploits a couple of ruby-specific shortcuts to achieve the final result.

```ruby
->l{1.step.find{|a|
```

This is easy: starting from 1, repeat until we find the right number.

```ruby
l.each_cons(a+1).all?{|*h,g|
```

Take every possible subarray of length a+1 and check.

```ruby
g==h.sum}}}
```

Is the last element the sum of all other elements?

So, what happens if no match is found?

After the last check, when a+1 is the length of the array, and `each_cons` returns the whole array, we try to get all subarray of length a+2 (length of the whole array plus 1), the list is empty, and that satisfies the `all?` check, so if no answer is found, the answer is the length of the array.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ā.Δ„üÿ.VO¨Å¿
```

Straight-forward modification of [my 5-bytes inversed approach from the related challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242947/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SKPeuSmPGuYd3nN4v16Y/6EVh1sP7f//P9pQx0jHRMdcx0LHCMgw1rEw0TE0M9ExNjKMBQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##XY09CsJAEIX7PcUglo/o/rhGCFppm84mWESzkIAYUcFK0EIPINbWHkIQjLWHyEVisgYEmeLNvPnmzTRcx8Us3FCfZmlknHQdThNDnkdDf8QGDcpPZ2oMitfBeV/y/TW7Zw9n7D9v2fH5KHZgFca2cTI3tDJhRMmCRSkjaqXLTeubVsvfA4@all2YIpATFgiUVSqvVUBCoWsd24FzcNfOv9KWVOhUW9GG1NAlKSSE0FBc14nVvVt6UBKuAtcKUvB6KW2AtkgPvD1hHw).

**Explanation:**

```python
ā             # Push a list in the range [1, input-length]
 .Δ           # Pop and find the first which is truthy for:
   „üÿ        #  Push string "üÿ", where the `ÿ` is automatically replaced with
              #  the integer using string interpolation
      .V      #  Execute it as 05AB1E code
              #  (`üN` creates all overlapping lists of size `N`)
        O     #  Sum each inner overlapping list
         ¨    #  Remove the last item
          Å¿  #  Check if the (implicit) input-list ends with this sublist
              # (after which the found result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 58 bytes

```hs
g n(h:t)l|t==init l=n|1>0=g(n+1)t$zipWith(+)t l
f l=g 1l l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVBNi8IwEL3nV8zBQ4td6CQ11oX0b3gQD8JqG4xZcXNa/O/dF2pxtQGFUHhfM33T7X6Oe@f6viWfdZ8hd9dgjPU2kDP@yk1p2szPOQ@zX3te29Bl8xyaOEBviR25/rSzngx9fQs6X6wPNKMDbdSWHrAsKL4nlpMsKFVQVdByar8JBTEA11PD09PT2cgvhrwsMVDDFOdJjJYSqGKd/M1hbx1dAHDXYFjjoyQnE2pcpsfoColyS328z0dDLO6HGSD/g0o8nAJMJZI3gCJFujwkLd5uPSx9qy6sC/GqZ@xU/gE)

Answer (score 3):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 12.5 bytes

```
/|,~==<*~$.`'.`,$>$_+$>@_
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWO_VrdOpsbW206lT0EtT1EnRU7FTitVXsHOIh8lBlN3WilaKNdBRMdBRMdRQMDXUUjAx0FIzNdBTMzIF8I2OggBGQZ2JoFqsUC9UEAA) / [All testcases](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RU5BCsJADLz3FXNYELSuTbLGldriT1oKCkLxot6kPsRLD4pv8Cn-xu1WkIEMk5kJub-Oh6Zpd6f-YfPcPC_n_dy_F9e0K4rNtDO2ntg6NaWpZqbcVqPf_-hzk4QRkFCcDIHDKqjIIAL5oP7QkHFYDg5nEIWGFAuYFY403hmaPmzgBN6B1EGYoiWxrDGwBmXjH18)

```
/|,~==<*~$.`'.`,$>$_+$>@_
/|,~                      Find first number n such that
    ==                     equals
      <*~                   take all except the last 
         $                   n items of
          .                  for each row of
           `'                 transpose
             .                 for each i in
              `,                range from 0 to (excluding)
                $                n
                 >              drop the first
                  $              i items of
                   _              input
                    +         sum of
                     $         the row
                      >     drop the first
                       @     n items of
                        _     input
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>18</s> 16 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
@ãX mx ¯J eUtX}a
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QONYIG14IK9KIGVVdFh9YQ&input=WzEsIDEsIDIsIDMsIDUsIDhd)

Port of [@lyxal's Vyxal answer.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243479/108687)

Explanation:

```sh
@             }a  # find the first positive integer X where:
 ãX               #   all overlapped sections of length X
    mx            #   sum each
       ¯J         #   remove the last item
          e       #   is this list equal to
           UtX    #   the last X elements of the input list?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 23 bytes

```
Ｉ⌕Ｅ⊕Ｌθ⬤θ∨‹μι⁼Σ✂θ⁻μιμ¹λ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYvBCsIwEER/JccNrIe0ooInEQXBotBj6SGkwQY20Sapvx83Fy87bx6zZtbRvDWV8owuZDjrlOHqwgSd/sAtmGi9DdlOcLfhlWdYpERxIoIFxSOyTQk8Csf2sqyaEvSrh56csXXSubD@BxyqvpOUNZjlsZRhUCgaFFsUexQH5lpaRjZqx6dt1DiWzZd@) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
     θ                  Input array
    Ｌ                   Length
   ⊕                    Incremented
  Ｅ                     Map over implicit range
       θ                Input array
      ⬤                 All elements satisfy
          μ             Current index
         ‹              Is less than
           ι            Outer value
        ∨               Logical Or
               θ        Input array
              ✂     ¹   Every element from
                 μ      Current index
                ⁻       Minus
                  ι     Outer value
                   μ    To current index
             Σ          Take the sum
            ⁼           Equals
                     λ  Current element
 ⌕                      Find first index of
                      ¹ Literal integer `1`
Ｉ                       Cast to string
                        Implicitly print
```

In Charcoal, the `Sum` of an empty list is `None`, so the test for a 0-binacci-like sequence always fails.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
+⁹\Ṗ;@ḣʋƑⱮJTḢ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/7UePOmIc7p1k7PNyx@FT3sYmPNq7zCnm4Y9H///@jDXUUjHQUTHQUzHUULIBsEMcYyASKGJoBCWMjw1gA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/7UePOmIc7p1k7PNyx@FT3sYmPNq7zCnm4Y9H/w@2Pmtb8/x8dbRzLpRNtpKMAQiCmIYIJpI11FEx0FMyhElCejoIhkGNoARVFQ2ZQrUCVphCVRgZArWZAGZBOI6AhRkZAnomhGcI@iLEWICkgB6jEAihiaAYkjI0MEcqMYcaawdRbApUZxHLFAgA).

#### How?

```
+⁹\Ṗ;@ḣʋƑⱮJTḢ - Link: list of integers, A
          J   - range of length of A -> [1,2,3,...,length(A)]
         Ɱ    - map (for L in [1,2,3,...,length(A)]) with:
        Ƒ     -   is A invariant under?:
       ʋ      -     last four links as a dyad - f(A, L)
 ⁹\           -       L-wise overlapping cumulative reduce A with:
+             -         addition
   Ṗ          -       remove the final value
      ḣ       -       head A to index L
    ;@        -       concatenate -> first L terms of A then summed terms
           T  - truthy (1-indexed) indices
            Ḣ - head
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 13 bytes

```
|L¹V€ṫ¹mhTm∫ṫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RUw5DgIxEPuQi52DIfyBEtFE6VdCqRAdDVvxl@UDafcn5CMhO4qEXNhjezw/7reW6/Jqz/NWrnX5fMu6lTxfcn2vXbfWYpSEyOjoTIMZAsXRHVcgAgW//zBvKg57yhPEYL3JAmaDko3F/T90DyoICjKFMI1QfMC8cgJNKf0A)

```
          m ṫ  # for each of the tails of the input
           ∫   # get the cumulative sums,
         T     # transpose this list-of-lists,
       mh      # and remove the last element of each;
   V€          # now check if this is one of
     ṫ¹        # the tails of the input
               # (and output the index if it is)
|L¹            # otherwise, output the length of the input
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 42 bytes

```
1//.a_/;MovingMap[Tr,#,a]!=2#~Drop~a:>a+1&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYy7CsJAFET7/IUspHE0ubvrGhXFwlZQtJMgFzGaIg9CtAnJr695EGSa4cxhEi7fz4TL@ME22lryvDnfvc0x@8bp68j57VpAgMPJVormUGR5w@sdT8m150/8LPenIk7Lm5jtor0I3eby4LSpnErVcCqJNl2hsUgoaCwH1lcQgYIB/GMGWWPR7dKHMjCtKxWkNNBkxtvuImghtEKgQUZDSRpX1V@Y3lmB/Nqp7Q8)

Uses the check from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243005/81203) to the challenge that inspired this one.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 11 bytes

```
fqsM.:PQT>Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P62w2FfPKiAwxC7w//9oQx0FIx0FEx0Fcx0FCyAbxDEGMoEihmZAwtjIMBYA)

#### Explanation

```
fqsM.:PQT>QT    # implicitly add T
                # implicitly assign Q = eval(input())
f               # return the first integer which satisfies lambda T
         >QT    # all but the first T elements of Q
 q              # is equal to
  sM            # map to their sums
    .:  T       # all sublists of length T of
      PQ        # all but the last element of Q
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 56 bytes

```julia
\(L,l=[0L])=sum(l)!=L&&1+L[2:end]\(l=[l;[L]];pop!.(l);l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9BbsMgEEX3OcUkiwhUGhnsEKeWcwL3BJgFUahERR1kO1Vv7w4QS1XRCPHn/fnA58M7w3@WpScd860qOk3b6fFFPN223X7PXzol3uxw0z1B7BvVad2Ee9ge0NJ4unzcR/BusOAGGK25xfNE6AZwGXaFFqbg3Uxin8EOXi@we1Jk9tt48m5ncwhmnCwxNLMwumH2A1Gm0dBeoE8E37GoUscMvlGCQaxV8j@yTLRkUDE4pU6VDM8OA46C14mIRP6VTEimGJw45glRYIREGhMEhgmBquJyvTS/IV9RR4wCbTV2uMStFDxZj6u1XOPlOnNGa5H/VPwC)

recursive function. At step `n`, `l` stores the `n` first sub-lists of length `length(L)-n` and `L` is the last one. We iterate until `sum(l)==L`

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 53 bytes

```
{first {none .rotor($^n+1=>-$n).map:{[R-] $_}},1..$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzBCoMwGINfJUgZG9Pi33adG@pD7Do28WBhMKtULyI@u6uKjBwSvoS0lfvquR5wMMjm0Xxc12O0ja3AXdM37sje9kxZHjF74nXZ3sfnI3qBFdMUEufe564cELACWY7RLE0A0zikMg@RCngtgfYgIKFw3dgaQQRKNvCX3sYKl6UXMaSG9lshIYSGIr3fLheJh1ASiQJpBSlob@V6odfNDRTn8w8)

- `first { ... }, 1 .. $_` returns the first number from 1 up to the size of the input list for which the brace-delimited anonymous function returns a true result.  Within that function, `$^n`/`$n` is the number being tested.  `$_` continues to refer to the input parameter to the outer function.
- `.rotor($^n + 1 => -$n)` produces a moving window of size `$n + 1` across the input list.  For example, if the input list is `1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 18` and we're testing whether the list is 2-bonacci-like, the rotor method returns a list of the lists `1, 3, 4`, `3, 4, 7`, `4, 7, 11`, and `7, 11, 18`.
- `.map: { [R-] $_ }` reduces each of those lists with the reversed subtraction operator `R-`.  (`a R- b` means `b - a`.)  Because the regular subtraction operator `-` is left-associative, the reversed subtraction operator is right-associative, and so to continue the above example, it produces the numbers `4 - 3 - 1`, `7 - 4 - 3`, `11 - 7 - 4`, and `18 - 11 - 7`.
- Finally, `none` returns a truthy result if none of the reduced lists has a truthy value; that is, if all of them are zero.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 123 bytes

The function takes an array of ints for `a` and its length for `z`.

```c
B(a,z,M,b,v,t,L)int*a;{int*c,*p;for(M=b=z;--b;M=v?M:b)for(c=a+z,v=0;c-b-a;v|=t)for(t=*--c,p=c-1,L=b;L--;)t-=*p--;return M;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJdb4IwFH3nV9y4mIDeLhQdc6t1yZ7lFzgfoLANszED6BIdv93dUqsO1xTae3rOPbcfir0pdTg8uzHuMMIEt1jj3MuLehCLvR4UDtbi9at0I5nInWAsEZHcPkWPiadRJePhDrfSF4olLBbbH1m3C7UcMKZwLRXjOJeJmDMmvJrJwZomZVZvygIi0Rxu8kJ9bNIMplWd5l@37zPnDMVVlZW1xqgW@IzzwvWcvQPUNKDiKqsWywX3lyBb1Ky1s1GD5yBA0P0S4tcQxSOEMcJ9h3hEETgFfNJZ7fSwk5KUd0YZ@JQqJIbOFFDSIKBozMPruozdRFMoIOqEEB7SbxTwa/rI2oRW90B0v2l5jXBOR/aRFXRiOpJ2Z0ZrhNy3H4msJi6q76zUMmn3azRBK9NBu0PSgHGiFwCuluYk8QUNU3igYTj0Otd0zk/MZ9fcaL5EU2i@9I6167Yuif3q9hY9T5zAk9XKWK3I6qgFBpwAa9pN008RegjWcrH616yfUp4Z9NOX4pJ8YUHFmh1cVHWamBfs2iMkhZR/6Y3jNIdf)

Comment: [120 bytes](https://tio.run/##bVJdT4MwFH3nV9zMLAF2ayibuFmric/jF8w9QEFlUbYAzmTKb5@3dN0msym09/Sce24/FHtVar/3Ffob8eQmuMMYU9xig3OvKBs/Ed8v68qNZSp3grFUxHL7GN@lnkaVTEY73MpAKJayRGx/ZNMtNNJnTOFGKsZxLlMxZ0x4DZP@hiZV3nxWJcSi3V8VpXr/zHK4r5usWF@/PTgnKKnrvGo0RpXAR1KUrud8O0BNAyqp83qxXPBgCbJDzVo3G7d4CkIE3c8hfglRPEaYINz2iAcUgVPAp73VXo96KUl5Y5RhQKkiYuhMISUNQ4omPLqsy9hNNYUCok4J4RH9xiG/pI@tTWR1M6IHbcdrhXM8sve8pBPTkbQ7M1oj5IH9SGQ1SVl/5ZWWSbtfowk7mQ66HZIGjBO9AHC1tCBJIGi4hxkNo5HXu6ZTfmI@ueZGiyWaQould6hdt01F7Bd3sBh44ggerVbGakVWBy0w4ARY036aYYYwQLCWi9W/ZsOM8jzAMHsuz8lnFlSs2cFZVceJecGuPUJSSPmX3jpOu/8F)