# Random Point from a 2D Donut Distribution

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic, geometry, random

A donut distribution (for lack of a better term) is a random distribution of points in a 2-dimensional plane, forming a donut-like shape. The distribution is defined by two parameters: the radius `r` and spread `s`, in which the distance to the origin follows a normal (Gaussian) distribution around `r`, with a standard deviation `s`. The angular distribution is uniform in the range `[0,2π)`.

### The challenge

Given a radius `r` and spread `s`, your code should yield the Cartesian (`(x,y)`) coordinates of a single point chosen from this distribution.

### Remarks

- Running your code multiple times with the same input should result in the specified distribution.
- Outputting polar coordinates is too trivial and not allowed.
- You can output Cartesian coordinates in any way allowed by the default I/O rules.

  - This includes complex values.

### Valid approaches

Several algorithms can be used to yield the desired distribution, including but not limited to

1. Choose `a` from the uniform distribution `[0,2π)` and `b` from the normal distribution `(r,s)`.
   Let `x = b*cos(a)` and `y = b*sin(a)`.
2. Choose `a` from the uniform distribution `[0,4)` and `b` from the normal distribution `(r,s)`.
   Let `x+y*i = b*i^a`.
3. Choose `a,b,c` all from the normal distribution `(0,1)`.
   Let `d = a+b*i` and `x+y*i = d/abs(d) * (c*s+r)`.

### Example distributions (N=1000)

`Below: r=1, s=0.1`

[image: r=1, s=0.1]

`Below: r=3, s=1`

[image: r=3, s=1]

`Below: r=1, s=0`

[image: r=1, s=0]

`Below: r=100, s=5`

[image: r=100, s=5]

Comment: _the distance to the origin follows a normal (Gaussian) distribution_ This is confusing, because any Gaussian distribution can produce negative numbers, and a distance cannot be negative. Your methods 1 and 2 (I haven't looked at what method 3 does) correspond to taking the absolute value of the Gaussian (and shifting the phase by 180 degrees, which is not significant)

Comment: @LuisMendo That's a valid point. The third method does basically the same. Consider *the distance* to be *the displacement in the chosen angular direction*.

Comment: @LuisMendo method 3 seems to be the same as methods 1 and 2, with the random angle generated as the direction of the vector formed by two iid normal variables.

Comment: re "lack of a better term": in math (complex analysis etc.) that's usually called ["annulus"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_(mathematics)).

Answer (score 8):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 38 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Takes `r` on the left and `s` on the right and returns a complex number.

```
{(⍺+⍵×(.5*⍨¯2×⍟?0)×1○○2×?0)×¯12○2×○?0}
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=q9Z41LtL@1Hv1sPTNfRMtR71rji03ujw9Ee98@0NNA9PN3w0vRuIgCJg7qH1hkYQLpC0N6gFAA&f=M1RIUzDQM@QyBtKGXIYgHpehgQGQNgUA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

Uses the first approach presented in the question. Dyalog doesn't have a builtin for sampling from a normal distribution, so this uses the [Box–Muller transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) to convert to random numbers from \$(0,1)\$ to a normally distributed value:

`(⍺+⍵×(.5*⍨¯2×⍟?0)×1○○2×?0)` draws a normally distributed value \$b \sim N(\alpha, \omega^2)\$:
`?0` random number \$c \in (0,1)\$
`1○○2×?0`: \$\sin(2\pi c)\$
`?0` random number \$d \in (0,1)\$
`.5*⍨¯2×⍟?0`: \$\sqrt{-2\ln{d}}\$
`⍺+⍵×` Scale from \$N(0, 1)\$ to \$N(\alpha, \omega^2)\$

`?0` generates a random number \$a \in (0,1)\$
`¯12○2×○?0`: \$e^{i 2\pi a} = \sin(2\pi a)i + cos(2\pi a)\$

The product of these two values is the result.

Plotting code and images:

```
'InitCauseway' ⎕CY 'sharpplot'
InitCauseway ⍬
sp←⎕NEW Causeway.SharpPlot(700)
sp.SetTrellis(2 2)
sp.TrellisStyle←4

F ← {(⍺+⍵×(.5*⍨¯2×⍟?0)×1○○2×?0)×¯12○2×○?0}

:For r s :In (1 0.1)(3 1)(1 0)(100 5)
    sp.NewCell
    sp.Heading←'r = ',(⍕r),'; s = ',⍕s
    sp.SetAxesScales(1)
    sp.DrawScatterPlot↓9 11∘.○{r F s}¨⍳1000
:EndFor

sp.SaveSvg(⊂'plot.svg')
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 10 bytes

```
Xr*+Jr4*^*
```

Inputs are `r`, then `s`. Output is a complex number.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P6JIS9uryEQrTuv/f0MuAz1DAA) Or see the plot for 1000 points at [**MATL Online**](https://matl.io/?code=xx1e3%3A%22%26G%0AXr%2a%2BJr4%2a%5E%2a%0A%5Dv%27.%27%26XG&inputs=1%0A0.1&version=22.4.0)! (it takes 10‒15 seconds).

#### How it works

Uses method 2 described in the challenge.

```
Xr   % Push random number with standard Gaussian distribution
*    % Implicit input: r. Multiply
+    % Implicit input: s. Add
J    % Push imaginary unit
r    % Push random number with stantard uniform distribution
4    % Push 4
*    % Multiply
^    % Power
*    % Multiply. Implicit output
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 56 bytes

```
[ normal-random-float 2pi random 2dup cos * -rot sin * ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYwxDsIwEAT7vGIVKQ0iEUkJD0A0NIgKKCwnBxbOnWVf3m8MEdXuzkpDxqrEfL2czsc9ouFRZsxGX50VTmpYE95T5MmvlBa26sr1myCJJdXxE4eq6rHr@nwDf6lvV1tLXoxiCO6vH8YlwErCBm0URXJc6iNb4z3qhrZo6M41QnSslD8)

Verifying correctness:

[image]

### Explanation

```
                      ! 1 0.1
normal-random-float   ! 1.091729295255315
2pi                   ! 1.091729295255315 6.283185307179586
random                ! 1.091729295255315 4.669140230445313
2dup                  ! 1.091729295255315 4.669140230445313 1.091729295255315 4.669140230445313
cos                   ! 1.091729295255315 4.669140230445313 1.091729295255315 -0.04323526873134136
*                     ! 1.091729295255315 4.669140230445313 -0.04720120946224146
-rot                  ! -0.04720120946224146 1.091729295255315 4.669140230445313
sin                   ! -0.04720120946224146 1.091729295255315 -0.9990649185802335
*                     ! -0.04720120946224146 -1.090708439475907
```

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 40 bytes

```r
function(r,s)rnorm(1,r,s)*1i^runif(1,,4)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/pflJKfV1pi@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NIp1izKC@/KFfDUAfE1jLMjCsqzctMA/J1TDShGjSKbA11im31DDX/AwA) or [plot the results at rdrr.io](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=rdonut%3Dfunction(r%2Cs)rnorm(1%2Cr%2Cs)*1i%5Erunif(1%2C%2C4)%0Aplot(sapply(1%3A1000%2Cfunction(x)rdonut(r%3D1%2Cs%3D.1)))%0A)

Comment: You could save a few bytes by using the R 4.1.0+ shorthand function definition notation:  `\(r,s)rnorm(1,r,s)*1i^runif(1,,4)`, though TIO doesn't seem to support it.

Comment: @user2554330 - Yes, but see comments [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243489/95126).  TLDR: changing a single ```function``` into ```\``` to save 7 bytes seems boring and I don't usually bother, since it's nice to have a TIO link.

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 42 bytes

```
Re[#+#2√Log[16/r^2]I^r]I^r&
r:=4Random[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7Pyg1Wllb2ehRxyyf/PRoQzP9ojijWM@4IhBW4yqysjUJSsxLyc@Njv0fUJSZV@KQFm2oYxD7HwA)

`RandomVariate@NormalDistribution` is costly (and, [as noted by Ben Izd](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243780), doesn't work with stdev=0), so this uses [Box-Muller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) to generate a normal distribution from two uniform ones.

Sample distributions (N=10000): 
[image]

Answer (score 5):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 26 bytes

```julia
r\s=(randn()s+r)im^4rand()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/vyim2FajKDEvJU9Ds1i7SDMzN84ExNXQ/J@WX6SQqZCZp2BoZWhgwFVQlJlXkpOnYRpjqMmVmpfyHwA)

uses the second formula. output is a complex number. `randn` gives a random number from a normal distribution (0,1), and `rand` from a uniform distribtion in [0,1)

1000 points from `10\1`:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica - 108 bytes

Following the first method, we could have:

```
fn=AngleVector/@RandomVariate[ProductDistribution[NormalDistribution[#,#2],UniformDistribution[{0,2Pi}]],1000]&;
```

then visualize it by:

```
visualize = 
  Graphics[{PointSize[.01], Point[fn[#, #2]]}, Frame -> True] &;
```

`r=1, s=0.1`:

[image]

`r=3, s=1`:

[image]

`r=100, s=5`:

[image]

Notes:

- `Variance: 0` in `NormalDistribution` is not supported (could be hacked by having a small number)

Comment: The question asks for one point, not 1000; those 1000 points are generated for illustration. [`Random[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Random.html) is a shorter way to access a uniform distribution. You can also save more bytes by using prefix/infix notation and `##` instead of `#,#2`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 58 bytes

Might not be the shortest, but here is the base-case for python i guess.

Outputs a complex number:

```python
lambda r,s:1j**uniform(0,4)*gauss(r,s)
from random import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcmxCoAgEADQva9w9ERCoynoT1oMuTI6lVOHvt6c3vDyV@8Ul4770V9Hp3eCddnso1SLAROTNHoFdblWihwFE3IiwS76QaCcuKqeOcQqUVptZgvQfw)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 45 bytes

```r
function(r,s)exp(runif(1)*2i*pi)*rnorm(1,r,s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NIp1gztaJAo6g0LzNNw1BTyyhTqyBTU6soL78oV8NQByT/HyihY6BnqPkfAA)

Uses the first method in the description, of course using the neat fact that \$e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)\$. Longer than [Dominic van Essen's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243790/67312) by 5 bytes, though.

Answer (score 3):

## Java 17, 127 bytes

```
(r,s)->{double a=new java.util.Random().nextGaussian(r,s),b=Math.random()*Math.PI*2;return new P(a*Math.cos(b),a*Math.sin(b));}
```

This is a `BiFunction<Double, Double, P>`
where P is a `record P(double x, double y) {}`

Comment: Try it online needs to update their JDK.

Comment: You should include the imports, so the `var g=new Random();` should be `var g=new java.util.Random();`. But you can golf the `var g=new java.util.Random();double a=g.nextGaussian(r,s),b=g.nextDouble(Math.PI*2);` to `double a=new java.util.Random().nextGaussian(r,s),b=Math.random()*Math.PI*2;` for -8 bytes.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks. updated. +2 bytes.. length still fits in Java's irritating signed byte 

Comment: Two more minor things to golf: `(r,s)->` can be `r->s->` for -1 byte and `return new P(a*Math.cos(b),a*Math.sin(b));` can be `return a*Math.cos(b)+","+a*Math.sin(b);` for another -3 (with the Bifunction replaced with a currying Function: `Function<Double, Function<Double, String>>`)

Comment: And if you haven't seen them yet, [tips for golfing Java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6671/52210) and [tips for golfing in 'all languages'](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tips-for-golfing-in-all-languages) might be interesting to read through. :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), <s>80</s> <s>70</s> 68 bytes

```
b=random(1,t)τ
f(r,s,t)=(normaldist(r,s).random(1,t)(cosb,sinb))[1]
```

Takes an extra argument `t` as the seed, which is the only way to re-use the function to get different samples without pressing the randomize button.

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ila0acz53f)

*-10 bytes thanks to [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)*

*-2 bytes thanks to [emanrescu A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100664/emanresu-a) (`\tau` to `τ`)*

All functions in Desmos are pure, so they can't return a different value when evaluated at different times, even in a list comprehension. This causes an issue with the CGSE policy of functions being re-usable.

There's a randomize button to re-seed all of the random seed-dependent function calls:
[image: Randomize]. This doesn't vibe with me because it requires user interaction to re-seed, but it would allow the following 53-byte submission:

```
b=random()τ
f(r,s)=(cosb,sinb)normaldist(r,s).random
```

In this submission, I opted to take the random seed as an extra argument, which is a common design decision in Desmos if a program needs to avoid user action when re-seeding. This is the only way to get different outputs from random functions without the user pressing the randomize button.

Comment: `τ` is two bytes shorter than `\tau`. Sorry about the edit, my mistake\

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 36 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
9°©D(ŸDÄ®>αÅ1*˜Ω®/*+žq·®*ÝΩ®/DÅ¾sÅ½‚*
```

Inputs in the order \$r,s\$.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f@NCGQytdNI7ucDnccmid3bmNh1sNtU7PObfy0Dp9Le2j@woPbT@0TuvwXLCAy@HWQ/uKgcTeRw2ztP7/N9Az5DIEAA) (With the `9` replaced with `3` so it won't time out.)

**Explanation:**

Uses the first method described in the challenge description.

However, 05AB1E lacks a Gaussian distribution random builtin, as well as a builtin to get a random decimal number given a range. Both of those are therefore done manually.

```python
9°©D(ŸDÄ®>αÅ1*˜Ω®/ # Push a random value with Gaussian distribution within the
                   # range [-1,1]:
9°                 #  Push 1,000,000,000 (10**9)
  ©                #  Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
   D               #  Duplicate it
    (              #  Negate the copy
     Ÿ             #  Pop both and push an integer-list list in the range
                   #  [-1000000000,1000000000]
      D            #  Duplicate this list
       Ä           #  Get the absolute value of each in the copy
        ®>α        #  Get the absolute difference between each and `®`+1
           Å1      #  Map each inner value to a list of that many 1s
             *     #  Multiply each to the values at the same positions in the
                   #  remaining list
              ˜    #  Flatten this list of lists
               Ω   #  Pop and push a random integer
                ®/ #  Divide it by `®`
*+                 # Use the inputs to transform it into s*random+r:
*                  #  Multiply it to the (implicit) input `s`
 +                 #  Add the (implicit) input `r`
žq·®*ÝΩ®/          # Push a random value with uniform distribution within the
                   # range [0,2π):
žq                 #  Push builtin PI: 3.141592653589793
  ·                #  Double it to get tau: 6.283185307179586
   ®*              #  Multiply it by `®`
     Ý             #  Pop and push an integer list in the range [0,2π®]
      Ω            #  Pop and push a random integer from this list
       ®/          #  Divide it by `®`
DÅ¾sÅ½‚*           # Calculate the resulting [x,y] pair using the two random
                   # values:
D                  #  Duplicate it
 Å¾                #  Pop and push its cosine
   s               #  Swap so the random value is at the top again
    Å½             #  Pop and push its sine
      ‚            #  Pair them together
       *           #  Multiply both to the earlier random value
                   # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```