# Consolidate an Array

Tags: code-golf, array

The task is simple: consolidate an array of ints. Consolidating this array consists of the following:

- All instances of 0 need to be moved to the end of the array.
- There should be no 0s between the non-zero integers.
- All non-zero indices should retain their order.

## Challenge

Consolidate an array in the least amount of bytes.

You are consolidating an array of random length with a size up to your language's max with random integers. Input may be any natural way for your language.

## Examples

Input

```
0 5 8 8 3 5 1 6 8 4 0 3 7 5 6 4 4 7 5 6 7 4 4 9 1 0 5 7 9 3 0 2 2 4 3 0 4 8 7 3 1 4 7 5 1 2 1 8 7 8 7 7 2 6 3 1 2 8 5 1 4 2 0 5 0 6 0 3
```

Output

```
5 8 8 3 5 1 6 8 4 3 7 5 6 4 4 7 5 6 7 4 4 9 1 5 7 9 3 2 2 4 3 4 8 7 3 1 4 7 5 1 2 1 8 7 8 7 7 2 6 3 1 2 8 5 1 4 2 5 6 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Input

```
-1 -7 -6 5 1 -5 -2 7 -3 -8 0 8 9 1 -8 -1 6 -4 1 -2 1 -7 5 4 -6 7 -3 9 8 3 -1 0 -5 -7 3 8 1 1 3 -3 -2 -2 0 -7 0 -4 8 6 -3 6 0 5 3 2 2 2 -2 -7 -3 9 -1 6 0 6 -7 9 4 -2 8 -8 -4 1 -8 4 3 7 3 5 1 0 3 3 7 -1 -5 1 -3 4 -7 0 3 2 -2 7 -3 0 0 2 -5 8 -3 -2 -7 -5 7 -3 -9 -7 5 8 -3 9 6 7 -2 4 7
```

Output

```
-1 -7 -6 5 1 -5 -2 7 -3 -8 8 9 1 -8 -1 6 -4 1 -2 1 -7 5 4 -6 7 -3 9 8 3 -1 -5 -7 3 8 1 1 3 -3 -2 -2 -7 -4 8 6 -3 6 5 3 2 2 2 -2 -7 -3 9 -1 6 6 -7 9 4 -2 8 -8 -4 1 -8 4 3 7 3 5 1 3 3 7 -1 -5 1 -3 4 -7 3 2 -2 7 -3 2 -5 8 -3 -2 -7 -5 7 -3 -9 -7 5 8 -3 9 6 7 -2 4 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

## Example Code (Java)

```
public class Consolidate {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int[] toConsolidate = new int[args.length];
        for (int i=0; i<args.length; i++){
            toConsolidate[i]=Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        }
        for (int i=0; i<toConsolidate.length; i++) {
            for (int k=0; k<toConsolidate.length-1; k++) {
                if (toConsolidate[k] == 0){
                    toConsolidate[k] = toConsolidate[k+1];
                    toConsolidate[k+1] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i:toConsolidate)
            System.out.print(i+" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Any integer or single digits like the examples?

Comment: @edc65 Any integer that your language supports.

Comment: How can the example be so complex when the shortest answers are 3 characters long? Is Java that much verbose?

Comment: @A.L in fairness, it is fully ungolfed and a terrible algorithm.

Comment: Isn't "There should be no 0s between the non-zero integers." redundant?

Comment: What if our language only supports one possible value besides the one that delimits the end of the array?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yes, but I put it there to make sure that I was understood (didn't have people shift all the zeroes one to the right or something like that.

Comment: @immibis Might not be the right language for this challenge. :P

Comment: @VoteToClose Did you see [my recent answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70532/11600)? This would be a zero-terminated cat program in Boolfuck: `,[;,]` - although it's still larger than the Pyth one.

Answer (score 31):

### Pyth, 3 bytes

```
!DQ
```

Explanation:

```
  Q    Input
!D     Sort by logical NOT
```

Try it [here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%21DQ&input=%5B0%2C+5%2C+8%2C+8%2C+3%2C+5%2C+1%2C+6%2C+8%2C+4%2C+0%2C+3%2C+7%2C+5%2C+6%2C+4%2C+4%2C+7%2C+5%2C+6%2C+7%2C+4%2C+4%2C+9%2C+1%2C+0%2C+5%2C+7%2C+9%2C+3%2C+0%2C+2%2C+2%2C+4%2C+3%2C+0%2C+4%2C+8%2C+7%2C+3%2C+1%2C+4%2C+7%2C+5%2C+1%2C+2%2C+1%2C+8%2C+7%2C+8%2C+7%2C+7%2C+2%2C+6%2C+3%2C+1%2C+2%2C+8%2C+5%2C+1%2C+4%2C+2%2C+0%2C+5%2C+0%2C+6%2C+0%2C+3%5D&debug=0).

Comment: `Q` can be implicit at the end of any Pyth script (assuming it's outside of a lambda, which this is), making this 2 bytes.

Comment: @hakr14 That feature didn't exist 2 years ago.

Answer (score 13):

## Jelly, 3 bytes

```
¬Ụị
```

Sorts the list by the logical NOT of its values. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=wqzhu6Thu4s&input=&args=WzAsIDUsIDgsIDgsIDMsIDUsIDEsIDYsIDgsIDQsIDAsIDMsIDcsIDUsIDYsIDQsIDQsIDcsIDUsIDYsIDcsIDQsIDQsIDksIDEsIDAsIDUsIDcsIDksIDMsIDAsIDIsIDIsIDQsIDMsIDAsIDQsIDgsIDcsIDMsIDEsIDQsIDcsIDUsIDEsIDIsIDEsIDgsIDcsIDgsIDcsIDcsIDIsIDYsIDMsIDEsIDIsIDgsIDUsIDEsIDQsIDIsIDAsIDUsIDAsIDYsIDAsIDNd)

#### How it works

```
¬Ụị    Main link. Input: A (list)

¬      Compute the logical NOT of each element of A.
 Ụ     Grade up; sort the resulting list's indices by their corresponding values.
  ị    Retrieve the elements of A at that indices.
```

Comment: Oh hey, modern Jelly can do a 2-byte `¬Þ`, even!

Answer (score 11):

## Octave, 18 bytes

```
@(A)[A(~~A) A(~A)]
```

`sort()` takes too many bytes. I'll just use logical indexing.

Examples on [ideone](http://ideone.com/yXZ7cp).

Comment: Nicely done. +1.

Comment: Wow, works in Matlab too! I didn't know that such indexing is possible

Answer (score 10):

## R, <s>29</s> <s>23</s> 21 bytes

As noted by MarcoBreitig, we can shorten it to 21 bytes if we don't need to provide it as a function:

```
x=scan();x[order(!x)]
```

---

Previous versions:

```
function(x)x[order(!x)]
```

The function takes a vector as input and orders by the logical vector that results from negating the input.

Original answer:

```
function(x)c(x[x!=0],x[x==0])
```

The function takes a vector as input and the concatenates (`c()`) the non-zero values and then the zero-values.

Comment: x=scan();x[order(!x)] is only 21 bytes long.

Comment: @MarcoBreitig, that's right. I thought it should be a function (and initially, the requirement was a "full-fledged program"). Will update my answer

Answer (score 8):

## [Retina](http://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 15

Simple repeated regex substitution:

```
+`\b0 (.*)
$1 0
```

[Try it online.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=K2BcYjAgKC4qKQokMSAw&input=MCA1IDggOCAzIDUgMSA2IDggNCAwIDMgNyA1IDYgNCA0IDcgNSA2IDcgNCA0IDkgMSAwIDUgNyA5IDMgMCAyIDIgNCAzIDAgNCA4IDcgMyAxIDQgNyA1IDEgMiAxIDggNyA4IDcgNyAyIDYgMyAxIDIgOCA1IDEgNCAyIDAgNSAwIDYgMCAz)

Comment: I used the same method in my Java answer (if I'm reading this right). :D

Answer (score 8):

### Python, 32 bytes

```py
lambda x:sorted(x,key=0..__eq__)
```

Takes argument as any iterable (list, tuple, etc.). Thanks to @xnor for teaching me a new trick!

Comment: It's a bit shorter to use `key=0..__eq__` (yes, two dots).

Comment: @xnor That's neat... How does it work?

Comment: Most Python objects have an equality method, so for example `"abc".__eq__("abc")==True`. It's what's called when you do `"abc"==`. [For reasons, Python integers don't have it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809932/python-why-does-the-int-class-not-have-rich-comparison-operators-like-lt) but floats do, and since `0. == 0`, we can substitute its equality operator., which is `0..__eq__`.

Comment: @xnor ahh, I knew about the `.__eq__` method, but the double dots were confusing me. I didn't catch that the first one was the decimal point in a float literal.

Answer (score 7):

### ES6, 23 bytes

```
a=>a.sort((x,y)=>!x-!y)
```

It used to be the case that `sort` wasn't stable, in which case you needed 41 bytes:

```
a=>a.filter(x=>x).concat(a.filter(x=>!x))
```

Answer (score 6):

## Python byte code (2.7.9), 252 bytes, 33 opcodes, 0.0228 seconds

This was build when the contest was still a [fastest-code](/questions/tagged/fastest-code) contest

Opens a file in the current directory called `'SourceArray'` for use

```
LOAD_CONST          ''
STORE_FAST          no_zeroes#  no_zeroes = ''

LOAD_NAME           open
LOAD_CONST          'SourceArray'
CALL_FUNCTION       0,1#  open('SourceArray')
LOAD_ATTR           read
CALL_FUNCTION       0,0#  .read()

LOAD_ATTR           split
CALL_FUNCTION       0,0#  .split()

DUP_TOP
DUP_TOP             #Start if
BUILD_LIST          0
COMPARE_OP          ==
POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE    35#  if list == [], GOTO 35
LOAD_ATTR           pop
LOAD_CONST          0
CALL_FUNCTION       0,1#  list.pop(0)
DUP_TOP
LOAD_CONST          '0'
COMPARE_OP          ==
POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE    28#  if list.pop(0) == '0', GOTO 28
PRINT_ITEM          #  print list.pop(0)
JUMP_ABSOLUTE       13

POP_TOP
LOAD_CONST          '0%_'#  '0 '
LOAD_FAST           no_zeroes
INPLACE_ADD
STORE_FAST          no_zeroes#  no_zeroes = no_zeroes + '0 '
JUMP_ABSOLUTE       13

LOAD_FAST           no_zeroes
PRINT_ITEM          #  print no_zeroes

LOAD_CONST          None
RETURN_VALUE
```

The `co_code` (The actual codey bit)

```
'd\x01\x00}\x00\x00\te\x00\x00\x83\x00\x00\tj\x01\x00\x83\x00\x00\t\x04\x04g\x00\x00k\x02\x00sG\x00j\x02\x00d\x02\x00\x83\x01\x00\x04d\x03\x00k\x02\x00s8\x00Gq\x15\x00\t\x01d\x04\x00|\x00\x007}\x00\x00q\x15\x00\t|\x00\x00G\td\x00\x00S'
```

Or a .pyc file version `03F3`

```
03 F3 0D 0A 40 FD B0 56 63 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 73 59 00 00 00 64 01 00 7D 00 00 09 65 00 00 64 02 00 83 01 00 6A 01 00 83 00 00 09 6A 02 00 83 00 00 09 04 04 67 00 00 6B 02 00 73 50 00 6A 03 00 64 03 00 83 01 00 04 64 04 00 6B 02 00 73 41 00 47 71 1E 00 09 01 64 05 00 7C 00 00 37 7D 00 00 71 1E 00 09 7C 00 00 47 09 64 00 00 53 28 06 00 00 00 4E 74 00 00 00 00 74 0B 00 00 00 53 6F 75 72 63 65 41 72 72 61 79 69 00 00 00 00 74 01 00 00 00 30 73 02 00 00 00 30 20 28 04 00 00 00 74 04 00 00 00 6F 70 65 6E 74 04 00 00 00 72 65 61 64 74 05 00 00 00 73 70 6C 69 74 74 03 00 00 00 70 6F 70 28 01 00 00 00 74 09 00 00 00 6E 6F 5F 7A 65 72 6F 65 73 28 00 00 00 00 28 00 00 00 00 74 09 00 00 00 70 79 6B 65 5F 63 6F 64 65 52 08 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 52 00 00 00 00
```

You can try to compile my source code yourself using [my library on github.](https://github.com/muddyfish/Python-PYKE) I just posted a commit to it that allowed comments so I hope this is still competing as far as [fastest-code](/questions/tagged/fastest-code) goes ;)

Roughly equivalent to

```
no_zeroes = ''
unamed_variable = open('SourceArray').read().split()
while unamed_variable != []:
    unamed_variable_2 = unamed_variable.pop()
    if unamed_variable_2 == '0':
        no_zeroes += '0 '
    else:
        print unamed_variable_2,
print no_zeroes,
```

Comment: Wooow. You cut a _ton_ of time off of that.

Comment: @VoteToClose that's about 1.5x the speed it ran on my laptop :O Who said Python was *that* slow?

Answer (score 6):

## Matlab: 21 bytes

```
@(a)[a(a~=0),a(a==0)]
```

Prints nonzero elements first, then concatenates with zero elements

`@(a)____` create an anonymous function with one input argument `a`

`[___,___]` concatenates horizontally vectors inside brackets, separated by commas

`a(a~=0)` returns vector with all nonzero elements of vector `a`

`a(a==0)` returns vector with all zero elements of vector `a`

Answer (score 6):

## APL: 8 bytes

```
(⍴a)↑a~0
```

a~0        remove zeros from a (read "a without 0")
(⍴a)       original length of a (read "shape of a")
↑          pad a without zeros to a's original length

Try it in http://ngn.github.com/apl/web/index.html

Test data:  a←1 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: You should either write a full program and read the input from stdin, or write a function and read the input from its parameters. But you can use `⍴↑{⍵~0}` and that's even shorter.

Comment: Not so fast.  ⍴↑{⍵~0} won't work everywhere, not in APL2000, nor in IBM APL2.

Comment: ⍴↑{⍵~0} will return an empty vector.  ⍴⍴↑{⍵~0} is a (one element vector) zero.

Answer (score 6):

## Zsh, 22 bytes

(input passed as arguments to the script/function (`$@` aka `$argv` array), output on stdout as space separated list, newline terminated)

```
<<<${@:#0}\ ${(M)@:#0}
```

- `<<< string`: here-string here passed as stdin to the `$NULLCMD` command (`cat` by default).
- `${@:#0}` `$@` except elements being 0.
- `${(M)@:#0}` reverse of the above

That assumes (like several other answers here) that zeroes in the input are all expressed as `0` (no `00` nor `0x0` nor `36#0`).

Comment: [verified on tio](https://tio.run/##VVG7bsMwDNzzFQSaIRkI6EFbcuEhP5A/6FKkAVKgqId0qpFvV@8oD6kFw0eKPB7Pv/dbuyzf9@Xr8@P953o4rm2e5/16en0JjzfZr4fz0XF77J7qJMggFSfjG2UEMuSyFMQjsG2oOJ5Qw44ClIESjjkydBaguHVE3ETP8S2IRr9NiAevSs4UkMe83fVyW0T5/JOnUbSIjt6jg2gCl2bRiq7qegCVytUYcKpSgLHLaydfT6mcDFRZURWZzOxQSkE@kKOSKruqARXJD4s2Lp9F1UoTjFfVNVjXYm5et5NGMlLXHklgfVDupM4Z3Ejlf9j0FEZ9z6lvU/tw34iWlyfDWvsD) :)

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, 26 bytes

```
f x=filter(/=0)x++[0|0<-x]
```

Take all non-zero numbers followed by all zeros. Filtering constants (here: `0`) is quite short when using a list comprehension: `[0|0<-x]`.

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 14 bytes

```
Sort[#,#!=0&]&
```

Comment: `Sort[#!=0&]` should be enough.

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript, <s>52</s> <s>54</s> 51 bytes

```
s=>s.replace(/\b0 /g,x=>++i&&'',i=0)+' 0'.repeat(i)
```

Comment: This doesn't work when the input does not contain any zeroes

Comment: @rink.attendant.6. Thanks, I've updated and still looking for some bytes off :)

Answer (score 4):

## Common Lisp, 46 bytes

```
(lambda(a)(stable-sort a(lambda(_ b)(= 0 b))))
```

Sort the array so that for each couple *(a,b)*, we have *a < b* if *b* is zero. When neither *a < b* or *b < a*, the sort is stable: the original order between elements is retained.

I also tried with *adjust-array* and *remove*, but this was too long:

```
(lambda(a)(adjust-array(remove 0 a)(length a):initial-element 0))
```

Answer (score 4):

### Java 7, 78 bytes

```
void g(int[]a){int c=0;for(int o:a)a[o==0?c:c++]=o;for(;c<a.length;a[c++]=0);}
```

I'm not sure why the other Java entries are using strings. If you want to filter an integer array, it seems best to use an integer array. This modifies the input in place by keeping two indices, then just filling the remaining slots with zeros.

Comment: Heh, I used it because I felt like it. I think you should be able to declare `o` with `int c=0,o;for(o:a)...`. You can also convert to Java 8 lambda syntax: `a->{int c=0;for(int o:a)a[o==0?c:c++]=o;for(;c<a.length;a[c++]=0);}` and state that it expects input as an int array.

Comment: Wait, scratch the o declaration thingy. But still, java 8 lambda. :D

Comment: @VoteToClose I thought it had to be self-contained. If I can declare types and stuff elsewhere without counting it, that doesn't seem right.

Comment: Since this is a function, input is passed to it by a previously executed statement anyways. The lambda can assume an input type, so its essentially the same.

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), <s>3</s> 2 bytes

```
µ¬
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C2%B5%C2%AC&inputs=0%205%208%208%203%205%201%206%208%204%200%203%207%205%206%204%204%207%205%206%207%204%204%209%201%200%205%207%209%203%200%202%202%204%203%200%204%208%207%203%201%204%207%205%201%202%201%208%207%208%207%207%202%206%203%201%202%208%205%201%204%202%200%205%200%206%200%203&header=%3F%C3%B0%2FvI&footer=)

Sort by logical negation. The header puts the input into a list format.

Answer (score 3):

## Perl 5, 26 bytes

23 plus three for `-an` (`-E` is free)

```
say for sort{!$a-!$b}@F
```

Thanks to [Dennis](/u/12012) for reminding me of `-a`, saving two bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>73</s> <s>71</s> <s>70</s> <s>52</s> <s>49</s> <s>48</s> 46 bytes - BIG thanks to [Ismael Miguel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/14732)

```
// Assuming
$a = array(4,8,6,1,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,-4,'-5',-1,564,0);

// Produces a notice-level error
foreach($a as$v)$v?print"$v ":$b.="0 ";echo$b;
```

Comment: `$v==0` can be replaced with `!$v`, saving you 2 bytes.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I see you did manage to cut a byte. Try this: `foreach($argv as$v)$v?$f.=" $v":$b.=" $v";echo$f.$b;`. It is.... some bytes, I don't know...

Comment: Or `foreach($a as$v)$v?print("$v "):$b.="$v ";echo$b;` for a more neat way, that looks exactly the same

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Nice! I would cry if I ever had to pick up someone else's project and found this level of code-golfing lol

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Shaved a few more!

Comment: I would cry as well. Good thing I also practice good coding conventions... Well, as far as Javascript and PHP allow. And I see you keep on improving it! Quite nice the few edges you're cleaning! They were nasty hick-ups I left behind. You deserve more upvotes.

Comment: Sadly, with the last change, your input method to run the code is invalid. However, you can say your code is PHP5.4, since it is now allowed to [use POST/GET parameters as input](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7591/14732). This allows you to say that your code is PHP4.1 and that you expect that the script is executed through Apache, with the GET key `a[]=<value>`. This will create your `$a` array for you. It relies on PHP4.1 directive [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) that was enabled by default on that version.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash + GNU utilities, 23

```
grep -v ^0 a
grep ^0 a
```

Assumes input is newline-separated entries in a file called `a`.  Score includes +1 for this filename.

Comment: @sch Yes, it should be bash - fixed.

Comment: @TimmyD yes - thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript ES6, 16 bytes

```
x=>x.sort(t=>!t)
```

Works on firefox

Answer (score 3):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 34 bytes

```
{for(;a++-NF;c?$++b=c:0)$a-=c=$a}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY@xDsIwDER/xUMHUGTJTVLiUlVsjPxDqMTCgMTCgPj24HNAqdqec34@19e9tfft8dwtNQS@nJftNIRwXbej7IfK67YO9TO2xiNxIT7QRPY3EUcymYiVhJRmVJXMdSDOEJG8Y6KMLvfOZkzwiBOKCTXXiGJChz2CuoChQCV7iUESRT8w/Vg@S2AqpjKu1DPkniVbE0YgsNgXij37CEDug1KHOlPsRBj0n6dA9T3nvo324b5RNEj5Ag)

This code runs through all the commandline arguments, shifts non-zero values to the left and clears arguments as it processes them.

The top of loop "should we iteration" condition expression is:

```
a++-NF
```

which increments `a` until it hits the number of commandline arguments `NF`.

The body of the loop,

```
$a-=c=$a
```

saves the value of the current commandline argument in variable `c`, then sets the current argument to 0.

At the end of each iteration, the ternery:

```
c?$++b=c:0
```

checks to see if the current argument `c` is non-zero and if so, increments the `b` (the number of non-zero argument found so far) and stores the current argument value in that slot.

After the code block processes the commandline arguments, the only left to do is trigger AWK to print all the commandline arguments with a `truthy` test without a code block.

```
1
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 5 [bytes](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=U0JDUyDihpAgK0BcMOKKlwpEZWNvZGUg4oaQIOKHjOKKjy0x4pa9wrEu4o2Y4ouv4oav4oqCwq8x4qe74ouv4qe7LOKHjOKItSjihpjCrzHii68rMjU2KSAtQFwwKzEKJnAg4oqCIjggYml0IGVuY29kaW5nOlx0IiBTQkNTICLih4ziio8tMeKWvcKxLuKNmOKLr-KGr-KKgsKvMeKnu-KLr-Knuyzih4ziiLUo4oaYwq8x4ouvKzI1NikiIOKKgitAXDDih6ExMjkiLiziiLY74oiYwqzCscKv4oy14oia4peL4oyK4oyI4oGFPeKJoDziiaQ-4omlKy3Dl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmt4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pah4oqU4omF4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqXL-KIp1xc4oi14omh4oi64oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oip4oqT4oqD4oqZ4ouF4o2Y4o2c4o2a4qyaJz_ijaPijaQh4o6L4oas4pqCzrfPgM-E4oiefl9bXXt9KCnCr0AkXCLihpB8IyIKJnAg4oqCImRlY29kZWQ6XHQiIERlY29kZSAiwqPCsS0xwrjChy7DjMKlwrPCsMKIMcKfwqXCnyzCo8K_KMK1wogxwqUrMjU2KSIg4oqCK0BcMOKHoTEyOSIuLOKItjviiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYU94omgPOKJpD7iiaUrLcOXw7fil7_igb_igpnihqfihqXiiKDip7vilrPih6HiiqLih4zima3ii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHiipTiiYXiip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_ihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipcv4oinXFziiLXiiaHiiLriip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziiKniipPiioPiipnii4XijZjijZzijZrirJonP-KNo-KNpCHijovihqzimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ5-X1tde30oKcKvQCRcIuKGkHwjIg==)

```
⊏⍏=0.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAg4oqP4o2PPTAuCgpmIFsxIDAgMiAwIMKvNSAwIDMgNCA1IDAgMCA2XQ==)

```
⊏⍏=0.
    .  # duplicate
  =0   # where is it equal to zero?
 ⍏     # rise (grade up)
⊏      # select
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 7 bytes

```
t~FT#S)
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dH5GVCNTKQ&input=WzAgNSA4IDggMyA1IDEgNiA4IDQgMCAzIDcgNSA2IDQgNCA3IDUgNiA3IDQgNCA5IDEgMCA1IDcgOSAzIDAgMiAyIDQgMyAwIDQgOCA3IDMgMSA0IDcgNSAxIDIgMSA4IDcgOCA3IDcgMiA2IDMgMSAyIDggNSAxIDQgMiAwIDUgMCA2IDAgM10)

```
t      % input array. Duplicate
~      % logical negate: nonzero values become false, zeros become true
FT#S   % sort (false, then true) and output a vector with the indices of the sorting
)      % apply that vector of indices to original array
```

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 6 bytes

```
{{!}$}
```

An anonymous function. Sort using “whether or not an element is zero” as a key.

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure/ClojureScript, 18 bytes

```
#(sort-by zero? %)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Seriously, 12 bytes

```
4,n`Y`M@░)░+
```

[Try it online!](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=NCxuYFlgTUDilpEp4paRKw&input=WzEsMiwwLDMsMV0)

Explanation:

```
4,n`Y`M@░)░+
4,n           push 4 copies of input
   `Y`M       map logical negate
       @░)    filter (take zeroes) and push to bottom of stack
          ░   filter (take non-zeroes)
           +  append zeroes
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Swift](https://swift.org/), 13 bytes

```
a.sort{$1==0}
```

Answer (score 2):

### TeX (Plain format), 160 bytes

Make the `0` character active (that is, make the interpreter process it as a command), then define that command to skip the character and increment a counter. At the end of the string, print as many zeros as were counted.

Save this as `zero.tex` and give the input through the command line with this command:

```
pdftex "\def\I{0 1 0 3 2 0 0 8 0 5 0 1 9 4}\input zero"
```

```tex
\def\I{}\newcount\Z\def\L{\loop\advance\Z by-1\ifnum\Z>00 \repeat}
\begingroup\catcode`\013 \def0{\advance\Z by1}
\scantokens\expandafter{\I\empty}\endgroup\L\bye
```

(Newlines added for clarity)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Perl6, 11 bytes

```
{.sort(!*)}
```

Produces a Block - which can be called on an array:

```
{.sort(!*)}.([1,2,0,3]).say
```

Although it would be more natural (and shorter) to write:

```
[1,2,0,3].sort(!*).say
```

How it works: if the [perl6 sort routine](http://doc.perl6.org/routine/sort) is called with a block which accepts only one argument, the list elements are sorted according to `by($a) cmp by($b)`. In this case, the block is `!*`, i.e. a negation of the [whatever operator](http://doc.perl6.org/routine/*#language_documentation_Terms).

I notice that:

- The example in the question is a class which provides a method, not including boilerplate required to read in
- The description of the task does not require printing, and, except for the fact that the example prints, implies that an array might be returned

Answer (score 2):

## J, 4 bytes

```
/:0=
```

Explanation:

```
/:      NB. upward sort on
  0=    NB. equality to zero
```

The sort function in J is guaranteed to be stable by the specification.

Alternative solution, 6 bytes:

```
#{.*#+
```

```
   *#+  NB. replicate each item by its sign (removing zeroes)
#{.     NB. take as many items from this as the original list had
        NB.  (taking more items than there are in a list results in extra zeroes)
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Straw](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/straw), <s>30</s> 29 bytes

```
<:([^0 ])()/,0()/ +,+( +) /}>
```

Use the CP437 encoding

#### Explanation

```
<:([^0 ])()/,0()/ +,+( +) /}>
<                             Take input
 :                            Duplicate
  ([^0 ])()/                  Remove every character that is not a 0 or a space
            ,                 Swap the two items on the top of the stack
             0()/             Remove every 0 on the top of the stack
                  +           Push a space and concatenate
                   ,          Swap
                    +         Concatenate
                     ( +) /   Remove duplicate spaces
                           }  Get the 'tail' of the string
                            > Output
```

[Try it online!](http://straw.tryitonline.net/#code=KDw6KFteMCBdKSgpLywwKCkvICssKyggKykgL30-Cj4pOiYm&input=MCA1IDggOCAzIDUgMSA2IDggNCAwIDMgNyA1IDYgNCA0IDcgNSA2IDcgNCA0IDkgMSAwIDUgNyA5IDMgMCAyIDIgNCAzIDAgNCA4IDcgMyAxIDQgNyA1IDEgMiAxIDggNyA4IDcgNyAyIDYgMyAxIDIgOCA1IDEgNCAyIDAgNSAwIDYgMCAzCi0xIC03IC02IDUgMSAtNSAtMiA3IC0zIC04IDAgOCA5IDEgLTggLTEgNiAtNCAxIC0yIDEgLTcgNSA0IC02IDcgLTMgOSA4IDMgLTEgMCAtNSAtNyAzIDggMSAxIDMgLTMgLTIgLTIgMCAtNyAwIC00IDggNiAtMyA2IDAgNSAzIDIgMiAyIC0yIC03IC0zIDkgLTEgNiAwIDYgLTcgOSA0IC0yIDggLTggLTQgMSAtOCA0IDMgNyAzIDUgMSAwIDMgMyA3IC0xIC01IDEgLTMgNCAtNyAwIDMgMiAtMiA3IC0zIDAgMCAyIC01IDggLTMgLTIgLTcgLTUgNyAtMyAtOSAtNyA1IDggLTMgOSA2IDcgLTIgNCA3) (The added code is to test all test cases)

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 7 bytes

```
{x@<~x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVLBagIxEL37FTn00B4Gkk12k9146H@IYC9bisWCeFgR/fXte5MVbFGpJYhvJjPz3rzsWjbvm3Hsu8PwOj8Nx3HXHZ4W@9O2682QV1/r/Lzq3z4@85D3efuyPM52C2tqk3A8/p1pgIKxiCLiBjhMKCpuUcOOCOSBKpygKKAzArmpw@HGaY6/iKjR2wpxrVWVTrLIg29mrui4p@Ks4azgP/y15uzPs4Qp4oxEI41WSm2kwgTxRhIqkvIDCnVKYEAuIW1gl9a2uozQL06gtoQqx6Rnh9AA5C1nJI7y6kU9baUVMs1SLnolXDvwKqmGULQUs4p5fD5GotodB4RC5MtQnWn1@YSuT3oio7JnW7ZJhVw3os0Rz3THm0eduekLCS48ue3In/y47salFw/78Puj0Q9n/AY)

`{` `}` anonymous function with argument `x`

`~` "not" - turn 0s into 1s, and everything else into 0s

`<` return the permutation for a stable ascending sort

`@` indexing

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 25 bytes

```ruby
->a{a-[0]+[0]*a.count(0)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVLLTsQwDLzzFTnyqFd5uE16gB@peihIewSE2ANCfHs3nYnDSunD0/F4bPfr8vqzn593edl@N1n8@lSvx@309nF5/773D3/7pzsvix/cOLiCk/AeBjch1MF5gBn4BERvwmzIjCxKZYQJYcRRCxWyGWG4kQqgBfvKewY4GTkCHy0xWjkPzuFzXe/QkVSG1GyZjC/1IRGSUtWkIKGY7yMWdi1KhHaE9pRaLXu2UQlbhjh7KsgK/JooI3R6MDz1CyslMz6CH@0g6b9WM8Y2hcNVskqzrr0LtXX1TXKBBKWNIlBcu6vUC7e63rYn/Dd6M5mQDXLuMyrdcJsU957Xdb8C)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 6 bytes

```
{0∨>}ᵒ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVIxTsQwEPyKdXWQbMeJneZ4SBStgAIKJCSaEzrRXHGCDt0rrqSh4TeXjwRnxmtOspLseHZ2djf3r3cPT2/PL49@2e825mZrNrvb@fg9Hw6X38/3y8/Xsrfzx3mbP0/LMprRNqZrTMJp8e0a0yMMjbEAI/AeSLgKoyIDsigVEbYIPU7QMEA2InRXUg40p7d8RoC9kj3wThO9lrPgrD6nxoySbyVnSq9cyS/xkJOsJAnkpJ7XWNixBCK0IrQWqFWyBx2TsF2Is5@ELMfbljJClyvDUj@xUqumO/C9HiT91yrG2KJwsIGsVKyH2kXQVdUtcnkEpYzCUTxUV20tXOpa3Zzwv6jNREI6yKHOKFXDZVLceZzM9Ac)

Other languages' "sort by logical negation" approach doesn't work here, because 1. Brachylog doesn't even have a concept of a Boolean and 2. `ᵒ` applies the default sort to elements that produce the same output to the given predicate, rather than preserving their order. Although, if the output is unbound but constrained... this happens.

```
{   }ᵒ    Sort the input by:
 0        this element is 0
  ∨       and the output is whatever, or whatever
   >      is greater than the output.
```

The very first solution I attempted was simply `>ᵒ`, which didn't rearrange anything at all, and when it came time to include that as an aside in my explanation of my original solution, I found I couldn't quite explain the circumstances, which led me to this.

The original, which is not without its own share of magic to begin with:

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 10 bytes

```
~b{ȧ>≜}ᵍcb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVIxTsQwEPyKdXWQYseJneZ4SBStyBVQICHRnNAJiiuQrkDiAfS0NDS8gG9cPhKcGa85yUqy49nZ2d1Mjze7u6f7h1u3HPYbc7U1m/31/Po1H4/nn9Pz@ft9eZkOv5/b@fSRorfdtCyDGerKtJWJOA2@bWU6hL4yNcAAvAPiL8KgSI8sSgWEDUKH4zX0kA0I7YWUBc3qLZ8BYKdkB7zVRKflanBWn2NlBkm3kjKlU66klzjISVKSCHJUz2ss7Fg8EVoRWvPUytm9jknYLsTZT0SW5W1DGaHLlVFTP7JSo6Zb8J0eJP3XysbYonCwnqyYrfvShddVlS1yeQQlj8JS3BdXTSmc69a6OeF/UZoJhHSQfZlRLIbzpLjzMJrxDw)

I arrived at this solution by trying the longer `~b{ȧ>≜}ᵍ↔ck`, only to discover that `ᵍ`... I actually don't know how this works. Not a clue. Somehow, the unbound variable created by `~b` always ends up non-zero, causing the group of non-zero items to appear before the group of zeroes, as intended (since groups are sorted by first appearance of their earliest elements).

`~b{ȧṡ}ᵍ↔ck` has the same length, and works on the same principle, but involves only more understandable behaviors of CLP(FD)--`ṡ` checks the case where its input and output are zero first, so the unbound variable created by `~b` simply ends up being zero:

```
~b            Un-behead the input, i.e. append something.
  {  }ᵍ       Group the elements by
    ṡ         sign of
   ȧ          absolute value.
       ↔      Reverse the groups, so that the one containing the first element is last,
        c     concatenate them,
         k    and remove the last element (the "something" from ~b).
```

Answer (score 2):

## x86 machine code, 17 bytes

Hexdump:

```
57 8b fa 33 c0 86 02 42 84 c0 74 01 aa e2 f4 5f
c3
```

A `fastcall` function: receives pointer to array in `edx` and its length in `ecx`.

Disassembled code:

```
    doit:
00D815D0 57                   push        edi  
00D815D1 8B FA                mov         edi,edx  
    myloop:
00D815D3 33 C0                xor         eax,eax  
00D815D5 86 02                xchg        al,byte ptr [edx]  
00D815D7 42                   inc         edx  
00D815D8 84 C0                test        al,al  
00D815DA 74 01                je          myskip (0D815DDh)  
00D815DC AA                   stos        byte ptr es:[edi]  
    myskip:
00D815DD E2 F4                loop        doit+3h (0D815D3h)  
00D815DF 5F                   pop         edi  
00D815E0 C3                   ret
```

Answer (score 2):

## [ArnoldC](https://lhartikk.github.io/ArnoldC/), 3752 bytes

Input is a 16 bit positive integer, where the first digit is disregarded. Wrote my own 'power' function, but I used the stock standard example for modulo function as per the ArnoldC website.
e.g. If you want to consolidate the array [3,1,0,2] you would do so as per the example below:

```
IT'S SHOWTIME
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE out
YOU SET US UP 0
GET YOUR ASS TO MARS out
DO IT NOW consolidate 13102
TALK TO THE HAND out
YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED

LISTEN TO ME VERY CAREFULLY consolidate
I NEED YOUR CLOTHES YOUR BOOTS AND YOUR MOTORCYCLE n
GIVE THESE PEOPLE AIR
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE ZeroCount
YOU SET US UP 0
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE NewNumber
YOU SET US UP 0
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE Modulus
YOU SET US UP 10
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE Power
YOU SET US UP 0
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE Decimal
YOU SET US UP 0
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE Digits
YOU SET US UP 0
GET YOUR ASS TO MARS Digits
DO IT NOW modulo n Modulus
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE Loop
YOU SET US UP 1
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE Cond1
YOU SET US UP 1
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE Cond2
YOU SET US UP 1
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE Val1
YOU SET US UP 0
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE Val2
YOU SET US UP 0
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE Val3
YOU SET US UP 0
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE FinalZeros
YOU SET US UP 1
GET TO THE CHOPPER Loop
HERE IS MY INVITATION n
LET OFF SOME STEAM BENNET Digits
ENOUGH TALK
GET TO THE CHOPPER Cond1
HERE IS MY INVITATION Modulus
HE HAD TO SPLIT 100
LET OFF SOME STEAM BENNET Digits
HE HAD TO SPLIT 10
CONSIDER THAT A DIVORCE Digits
YOU ARE NOT YOU YOU ARE ME 0
ENOUGH TALK
STICK AROUND Loop
BECAUSE I'M GOING TO SAY PLEASE Cond1
GET TO THE CHOPPER ZeroCount
HERE IS MY INVITATION ZeroCount
GET UP 1
ENOUGH TALK
BULLSHIT
GET YOUR ASS TO MARS Val1
DO IT NOW pow 10 Power
GET TO THE CHOPPER Val1
HERE IS MY INVITATION Digits
HE HAD TO SPLIT Val1
ENOUGH TALK
GET YOUR ASS TO MARS Val2
DO IT NOW pow 10 Decimal
GET TO THE CHOPPER Val1
HERE IS MY INVITATION Val1
YOU'RE FIRED Val2
ENOUGH TALK
GET TO THE CHOPPER NewNumber
HERE IS MY INVITATION NewNumber
GET UP Val1
ENOUGH TALK
GET TO THE CHOPPER Decimal
HERE IS MY INVITATION Decimal
GET UP 1
ENOUGH TALK
YOU HAVE NO RESPECT FOR LOGIC
GET TO THE CHOPPER Modulus
HERE IS MY INVITATION Modulus
YOU'RE FIRED 10
ENOUGH TALK
GET TO THE CHOPPER Power
HERE IS MY INVITATION Power
GET UP 1
ENOUGH TALK
GET YOUR ASS TO MARS Digits
DO IT NOW modulo n Modulus
GET TO THE CHOPPER Val3
HERE IS MY INVITATION Digits
HE HAD TO SPLIT 10
ENOUGH TALK
GET TO THE CHOPPER Cond1
HERE IS MY INVITATION Modulus
HE HAD TO SPLIT 100
LET OFF SOME STEAM BENNET Val3
ENOUGH TALK
GET TO THE CHOPPER Cond2
HERE IS MY INVITATION Digits
YOU ARE NOT YOU YOU ARE ME 0
ENOUGH TALK
GET TO THE CHOPPER Cond1
HERE IS MY INVITATION Cond1
CONSIDER THAT A DIVORCE Cond2
ENOUGH TALK
GET TO THE CHOPPER Loop
HERE IS MY INVITATION n
LET OFF SOME STEAM BENNET Digits
ENOUGH TALK
CHILL
GET YOUR ASS TO MARS FinalZeros
DO IT NOW pow 10 ZeroCount
GET TO THE CHOPPER NewNumber
HERE IS MY INVITATION NewNumber
YOU'RE FIRED FinalZeros
ENOUGH TALK
I'LL BE BACK NewNumber
HASTA LA VISTA, BABY


LISTEN TO ME VERY CAREFULLY pow
I NEED YOUR CLOTHES YOUR BOOTS AND YOUR MOTORCYCLE base
I NEED YOUR CLOTHES YOUR BOOTS AND YOUR MOTORCYCLE exponent
GIVE THESE PEOPLE AIR
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE result
YOU SET US UP 1
STICK AROUND exponent
GET TO THE CHOPPER result
HERE IS MY INVITATION base
YOU'RE FIRED result
ENOUGH TALK
GET TO THE CHOPPER exponent
HERE IS MY INVITATION exponent
GET DOWN 1
ENOUGH TALK
CHILL
I'LL BE BACK result
HASTA LA VISTA, BABY

LISTEN TO ME VERY CAREFULLY modulo
I NEED YOUR CLOTHES YOUR BOOTS AND YOUR MOTORCYCLE dividend
I NEED YOUR CLOTHES YOUR BOOTS AND YOUR MOTORCYCLE divisor
GIVE THESE PEOPLE AIR
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE quotient
YOU SET US UP 0
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE remainder
YOU SET US UP 0
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE product
YOU SET US UP 0
GET TO THE CHOPPER quotient
HERE IS MY INVITATION dividend
HE HAD TO SPLIT divisor
ENOUGH TALK
GET TO THE CHOPPER product
HERE IS MY INVITATION divisor
YOU'RE FIRED quotient
ENOUGH TALK
GET TO THE CHOPPER remainder
HERE IS MY INVITATION dividend
GET DOWN product
ENOUGH TALK
I'LL BE BACK remainder
HASTA LA VISTA, BABY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVdNk6IwEL3zK/rmZQ/q/IIIUVILCUWiU@7NEWqLKiWuHzv7790G5EuiMNbcJOl0v379uhM3x1Tvou31ytRIgnTFu2I@tVy6BtsNmVQ@kaBCSkFfztZaLEFSBUsJywDG1gJ/41oIRKKVAJ@EMjd0BDAFXLzDVqcnvUuizTmGydtkPLUU8X5mxsql4BLuVJ5dsqIwo5SDoqHPOFHUsSwPQWRL6J3CioYIjIR0vvS8ddO5xYBT6hRwbE@gd1l8zIRQErJA@acvlAjtte1RSK0Fw5CZKYWAigDXCAtN2f@Kj9rWl7TLgcGYx5/8sv@Ij0OMfR1ddpfTnenEaBvoz2FOnXib7De7QabJ7@R8Glbam21d3X0GXkNaZWEI4Gl9uM/OZGfrNJoMNZwOMVxtdpMhFKDddKDd2xC7eZJudpliOlXNab1p33ZFENCw4MelIQUmwV8D4yumiGKCo0A9tBfzOUiB6sdGID52COe4eqsF5WK5cCFrKpPzglSz97pm2HpOdlIGHhZ2Mh73x@0esmzBJXMwqHKJAgIOW2GntRSGnYu6yZUF5TcGGLfSkIrZP3FLLLFnc3Zm1CZL7FE28mEhGF/kcckasGOJLKVjSL9uWzMF9X52OK9QE8kMp4x0mTJ3Qy6vuhcO@hNZuPWoAUtubobxgNP8xH2BTTCmXRjlBPgakLJjRrg5ZyHO09x7j8jqeWf2Wu/fWDYmdue0TOABY430OmWrLhMuIKQyoLaCucBOEwtmm2LVnfCsT1q8TMZ9CRRCMLusRdIB/@LgNdf57WuC60/q@@dJjnJA1OnzVAZPly8mVew9Gm0FsB733zfgbZd5nlkhjTunMwvaU@7l5m3pvxGviZCNPA8TgBnBEd5wTaQi4BFY4T1JfuD2bG09f9sh9lfedB@b00tvwfjfQadxRtHQJ@ExPl12584N37q9aq9d4m/nzaznabQIv5n3aK0KaHbbwuOId343fAqBtYpYwjRW8FkBixH1Si2i5G8SxWn06tmTPg4v45@LPifxsIf9Md5vkjQa9gY/HJGArflP013VKgzmqlV83E/WMtkeUZRIHnvPnLTUViHqcV0z0gO9ElwJ5uHUaLg0aO56/Q8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 22 bytes

```julia
l->[l[l.!=0];l[l.==0]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU9BCgIxDLz7ivG2HirZtmu7yPqRZQ8iCkoRERUP/n3NpEpKm0knk8nlWc779j2fhrm43VjGsl4OMm2ZDJpMcxlG18IluA06aNbBeSgMcBmCjJ7VDGVt4CKBh3V0iOwybq/EQI6YQlKQldWyGNihR1gXamRKBb1ERQK8BUk/LZslJCVFkV/ZPMTqJWoTR9Cw6EvkzHtLgVgHhSpqmqLhSch/P4mo7tnXbXIdbht5FUkTPju8jofF7X6@Psq1OTVltZq/)

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Þ~
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWiw_Pq1tSnJRcDOUvuHkm2kBHwVRHwQKMjMFsQx0FMzDXREfBACxoDhY3A4uYIHHNYSKWYF0Qo8zBXGMw1wiMTGBcE7Cx5mCuIZJRhmBlhjBZCGkOFjSDKTYCi5vCNBrBrDMAqwG5MxbiKQA)

Sort the input (`Þ`) by logical NOT (`~`).

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

Code:

```
ED0¢r0KR`rFZ}|
```

Explanation:

```
E               # Evaluate input
 D              # Duplicate top of the stack
  0¢            # Count zeroes
    r           # Reverse stack
     0K         # Delete all zeroes
       R        # Reverse top of the stack
        `       # Flatten
         r      # Reverse stack
          FZ}   # For N in range(amount zeroes): push zero
             |  # Print full stack
```

Uses CP-1252 encoding. Takes an array like this:

```
[0, 5, 8, 8, 3, 5, 1, 6, 8, 4, 0, 3, 7, 5, 6, 4, 4, 7, 5, 6, 7, 4, 4, 9, 1, 0, 5, 7, 9, 3, 0, 2, 2, 4, 3, 0, 4, 8, 7, 3, 1, 4, 7, 5, 1, 2, 1, 8, 7, 8, 7, 7, 2, 6, 3, 1, 2, 8, 5, 1, 4, 2, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java, <s>131</s> <s>138</s> 136 bytes

Thanks to @t0r0X for pointing out a flaw in my code! (and @Mego for pointing out how to fix it!)

```
void x(String y){int z=y.length(),i=0;System.out.print(y=y.replaceAll("( 0)|(0 )",""));for(;i<z-y.length();i+=2)System.out.print(" 0");}
```

Expects input as a string in the format `"1 2 3 4 5 0 6 0 7 8 9"`.

Comment: @t0r0X I don't think so; do you mean that it's missing a space after the 0? or it looks like `00`?

Comment: Cool. Space is missing before `0` in last print(). I.e. `print("0")` should be `print(" 0")`. Code length is indeed 138 chars.

Comment: @t0r0X I guess that got clipped somehow. ;P

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 28 chars

Given input array `i`, e.g. `def i = [ 0, 5, -1, 3... ]`, the following delivers the solution:

```groovy
i.findAll{it}+i.findAll{!it}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 8 bytes

```
Un@!X-!Y
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VW5AIVgtIVk=&input=WzAgNSA4IDggMyA1IDEgNiA4IDQgMCAzIDcgNSA2IDQgNCA3IDUgNiA3IDQgNCA5IDEgMCA1IDcgOSAzIDAgMiAyIDQgMyAwIDQgOCA3IDMgMSA0IDcgNSAxIDIgMSA4IDcgOCA3IDcgMiA2IDMgMSAyIDggNSAxIDQgMiAwIDUgMCA2IDAgM10=)

Joining the "sort by logical NOT" party, as that's literally all it is.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 84 <s>99</s> chars

Now even shorter than ever... based on **previous answer and suggestions by @VoteToClose** ;-)

```java
y->{int z=y.length();for(y=y.replaceAll(" 0|0 ","");y.length()<z;)y+=" 0";return y;}
```

Java <= 7 version, 99 chars:

```java
String x(String y){int z=y.length();for(y=y.replaceAll(" 0|0 ","");y.length()<z;)y+=" 0";return y;}
```

Comment: Use Java 8 lambda syntax: `y->{int z=y.length(),i=0;y=y.replaceAll("0 *","").trim();for(int n=y.length();i<z-n;i+=2)y+=" 0";return y;}`

Comment: Nah, you take it. c: Keep it in this answer, though.

Comment: Sorry, I mean to replace the for loop with `for(;z!=y.length();)y+=" 0";`.

Comment: You can get rid of `,i=0` now.

Comment: You can use `y=y.replaceAll("( 0)|(0 )","")` instead of `y=y.replaceAll("0 *","").trim()`.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after I commented. The suggestion I just put is a byte shorter. :P

Comment: Shaving another byte: `int z=y.length();for(y=y.replaceAll("( 0|0 )","");y.length()<z;)y+=" 0";`

Comment: And again two. THX for the fun!

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica 33 bytes

```
DeleteCases[#,0]~Join~Cases[#,0]&
```

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell, 31 bytes

```
param($a)($a|?{$_})+($a|?{!$_})
```

Takes input `$a`, then does a `Where-Object` (the `?`) for all elements that are true (i.e., not zero), and joins that with another `Where-Object` for all elements that are false (i.e., zero).

Comment: You can make it even shorter by using splatting [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY1BCsMgEEX3nsKClIRYUGM0XYT2JqUU0y4CEbPoIs3ZzXcIZRDfm5mvcf6GtHzCNF1ecwpZjMOaK/FM7@V3W8Vjq5u/nYrmjTER@cArJTvZo1rcWjqQlQrm4Q5sD/LEV@yUhAe1IIOyRBZJD9JHQmOiqVeOhzmaGnhHW4ZeUujjv5qxsxj5PeYd "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")

Comment: And using the `-ne` and `-eq` operators [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3BCsMgDIbvPoUHGZVZUGvNdijsVcaw26Gs1h52GHt29zdICPn@JH@S108q@ystS/9YS6pqnr61U/fy3Pt3svrcOG1W158QKstJdtaM5oIYUJ2JoGAsFEFHcGhEzFfsHA4CDSCPCEwBTgK55nCYOO4dSVCRpx565C3Plyz6@KeFOKlZ3nL9Aw "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [8th](http://8th-dev.com/), 75 bytes

First create an array with elements not equal to zero. Then append all found zeros to resulting array.

SED (Stack Effect Diagram) is `a -- a`

**Code**

```
0 swap ( not if n:1+ false else true then ) a:filter ( 0 a:push ) rot times
```

**Example**

```
ok> [0, -3, 7, 0 ,0 , 14, -1] 0 swap ( not if n:1+ false else true then ) a:filter ( 0 a:push ) rot times .
[-3,7,14,-1,0,0,0]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 47 bytes

```
proc D L {proc S x\ y {expr !$x}
lsort -c S $L}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LVG7bsMwDNz9FWyQlYD1sCXvGbNlTDsUQTcXMRwHcGHo2907yhAMH8Xj8Ugtj3Hfp/n5kItcZTN0k/VT/mT7WadZPs5racbXc15EmTpfyz7@fk9kN1srnWScgL@THihKiygh7oHjgZLhARxWJKAA5HGioYjKBOSOCoeMszt@CVFvWY@4M5Y3pRb36FeaTZ1oEu0trZ2oR5kG0QxCttaASpMaGbCBsldklXEHm0Rpkgo0lMFyvAysUHbFfUuNTKlgBjowvB2SDi3rRYPKeSNT2TzE6iXanurmuDNGat4dBWJtFKqoaba2M@XKDz@JUZ1zqNPk2twm4nZTKXio6b285H7B631VfDqVff8H)

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 47 bytes

```
proc S x\ y {expr !$x}
proc D L {lsort -c S $L}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LVG7bsMwDNz9FWyQlYD1sCXvGbNlTDsUQTcXMRwHcGHo2907yhAMH6kj70gtj3Hfp/n5kJusn/In2886zfJxXktj6YtcZRtfz3kRJel8Lfv4@z0x3WytdJJxAv5OeqAoLaKEuAeOB0qGB3BYkYACkMeJhiIqE5A7KhxunOX4JUS93XrEnbG8dWqRh15pNnWiSbS3a@1EPco0iGYQskkDKk1qZEABpVZklXEHm0Rpkh1oKIPlmAysUKoi37JHZqtgBjowvB2Sjl6mRYPKeSOvsnmI1Uu0PdXNcWeM1Lw7NohVKNSm1rO1nSlXfvhJjOqcQ50mV3GbiNtNpeChpvfykvsFr/dV8elU9v0f)

---

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 53 bytes

```
proc D L {lsort -c [list apply {x\ y {expr !$x}}] $L}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LVFBjoMwDLz3Fd6qV0uEBBLuPfYH3R4qtIeVWDWirMQK5e3sjIMiYBzbM2OzjNO@5/k1ylVusk3v17yIjnKfvt@LPHOe/mRbPwXvrzXP8nFZS3nI5Vb26eeZ2XPaGukk4Xh8nfRAQRpEEXEPHA4UDQ@oYUcE8kAtTjAU0BmB3NHhkHF2xyci6i3bIu6sqjWmBvfQK6dNnWgU7S2tnWiLNvWiCQXJpAGVJjUwoIBSK7DLagebRGmSDDSUUOV46dmhVMV9Q45EKm8GOlS0dlh0cJkWDSrnDUwl8xCql2B7qpvjzhipeXckCFXIV1LjbGxnypUffiKjOudQp0lV3CbidmMp@FH5d3nL/Yq/96j4fC77/g8)

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 55 bytes

```
proc S x\ y {expr abs($x)<!$x}
proc D L {lsort -c S $L}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LVExbsMwDNzzCjbw0A4ELEu2ZKBjxmwd2w5p0M1FDNsFXBh6u3tHGUKQI3k8HunlPuz7OD3u8ibrh/zJ9r2Ok9y@5udqfXl9qtZ8svJFrrIN82NaREmurnkffm4j06etllYSnse/kw4oSI0oIu6Aw4Gi4R4cdkQgD9TgBUMBnRHIHR0OFWc5/iKizqoN4tZYjSnVyGNePm3qRKNoZ2VtRRu0qRdNICQbDag0qYEBByhnBXYZt7dNlCapQEMJLMekZ4dyKvI1NRKlvBlowWjskXRo2SwaVO4bWErmIRQvwe5ULsebMVLz7igQyiBfRE2ztpspT374iYzKnn3ZJpXhthGvG3PGhxp/l1neL/h6nwWfz3nf/wE)

---

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 61 bytes

```
proc D L {lsort -c [list apply {x\ y {expr abs($x)<!$x}}] $L}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LVFBboQwDLzvK9wVh/ZgiUAgQepxj/uD7R7oqodKVIuASlQob6czDoqAcWzPjM3yGPZ9nJ4PuchVtmF@TovoQ27D97xIP47Dn2zrh@D9tY6T9J/za7G@vb8Ua0p3Ka5pH376kb2nrZRGIk6Nr5MWyEuJKCBugf2BguEONewIQDVQheMNeXQGIHd0OGSc3fEJiFrLVogbq6qMqcQ99NJpUycaRFtLayNaoU1r0YiCaNKASpPqGVBAqeXZZbWdTaI0SQYaiqhyvKzZoVTFfUmOSKraDDSoqOyw6OAyLRpUzuuZiubBZy/e9pQ3x50xUvPuSOCzUJ1JjbO0nSlXfvgJjPKcXZ4mZnGbiNsNKeFHjb/LLLcL/t494/M57fs/)

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 70 bytes

```
proc D L {concat [lsearch -al -inl -not $L 0] [lsearch -al -inl $L 0]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHLboMwELznK1ZRryvZ2GBzzzF/EOWAUKVWooASekL@djqz5lhZ4NnX7Ox6G6fjWF/LKDe5yz4u8zhs8pjen8Nr/BIdJtHvGb952eTjLu75T9D85Zh@hpUkl91JKxkn4PbSAUVxsBLsDjieKBnukcOKBBSAGpxoKKIyAfmzwiPizccvweos2sBuLasxJgc/@pXLrl40iXYW1la0QZkG0YyEbK0BlSI10mADZa/IKsvtbRKlSDJQUEaWpzOwQtkVfkeOTKpgAlpkNHaYdHJZLwpUzhsZyqYhVi3R9lQ3x53RUtPuSRBro1BJjdPZzpQrP/UkWnXOvk6Ta3ObiNtNpeCh1t/tLY8bHvBZ8fVajuMP)

Comment: Failed outgolf: https://tio.run/##LVFBisMwDLz3FUPpVRAnTuz23GNuPZYeginsQrYJbRYWgt@e1cjBhI6kkWakLmnctvk9JdyQsI6f5/BOX5BhhHy/RpwSTpdLjyrjYLQr/rCm6ZWGBfcb5DUtDwPPR97Gn2FGj/WwVmgR9TX669Ap8qg0Chp3iv2OguGzctgRFDWKan3ekNfOoMjtHU4rznL8gkadVWuNW2PVNqnSvOrlwyoOEiCdlaWF1NomDSQqIZq0QqFJ8QwoINTy7DLu2TYRmuQEGorKckw27BCqar7ijMhRjRlolVHbI2mfZVo0KNzXsxTNgy9evN2pXI43YyTm3XGAL0JNGWozK7uZ8OS7n8Co7Hku28QibhvxuiFn/aPm3@WD@xWn/lHw8Zi37R8

Comment: Failed outgolf: https://tio.run/##LVFBjoMwDLzzCm/VqyVCAgn3HvuD3T1UaG@siiiVWEV5OzvjoAgYx@Px2GzTfBzL@pzkJnfJ8@u5bqKT5MeyzH@S9y/B@2dfVvm47qUUud7LMf8@FtKb3EovCcfj62QACtIiiogH4HCiaHgEhxURyAN1OMFQQGUEcmeFQ8bZHZ@IaLBsh7g3VmdKLe7RrzRZnWgUHSytvWiHMvWiCYRkrQGVJjUwYANlr8Aq4442idIkFWgogeV46Vmh7Ir7lhqJUt4M9GB0dkg6tawXDSrnDUwl8xCql2B7qpvjzhipeXcUCLWRr6Km2drOlCs//URGdc6xTpNqc5uI2434Z7lZ3ttLPm/4e98VXy7lOP4B

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 bytes

```
{!oJ
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7B%21oJ&i=[0+5+8+8+3+5+1+6+8+4+0+3+7+5+6+4+4+7+5+6+7+4+4+9+1+0+5+7+9+3+0+2+2+4+3+0+4+8+7+3+1+4+7+5+1+2+1+8+7+8+7+7+2+6+3+1+2+8+5+1+4+2+0+5+0+6+0+3]&a=1)

Sort using `x!=0` as the key.

### 5 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╦╤∩öµ
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=cbd1ef94e6&i=[0+5+8+8+3+5+1+6+8+4+0+3+7+5+6+4+4+7+5+6+7+4+4+9+1+0+5+7+9+3+0+2+2+4+3+0+4+8+7+3+1+4+7+5+1+2+1+8+7+8+7+7+2+6+3+1+2+8+5+1+4+2+0+5+0+6+0+3]&a=1)

Filter out zeros and pad to input length.

Answer (score 1):

### Pyth, 2 bytes

```
o!
```

[**Test suite**](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=o%21&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B0%2C5%2C8%2C8%2C3%2C5%2C1%2C6%2C8%2C4%2C0%2C3%2C7%2C5%2C6%2C4%2C4%2C7%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C4%2C4%2C9%2C1%2C0%2C5%2C7%2C9%2C3%2C0%2C2%2C2%2C4%2C3%2C0%2C4%2C8%2C7%2C3%2C1%2C4%2C7%2C5%2C1%2C2%2C1%2C8%2C7%2C8%2C7%2C7%2C2%2C6%2C3%2C1%2C2%2C8%2C5%2C1%2C4%2C2%2C0%2C5%2C0%2C6%2C0%2C3%5D%0A%5B-1%2C-7%2C-6%2C5%2C1%2C-5%2C-2%2C7%2C-3%2C-8%2C0%2C8%2C9%2C1%2C-8%2C-1%2C6%2C-4%2C1%2C-2%2C1%2C-7%2C5%2C4%2C-6%2C7%2C-3%2C9%2C8%2C3%2C-1%2C0%2C-5%2C-7%2C3%2C8%2C1%2C1%2C3%2C-3%2C-2%2C-2%2C0%2C-7%2C0%2C-4%2C8%2C6%2C-3%2C6%2C0%2C5%2C3%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C-2%2C-7%2C-3%2C9%2C-1%2C6%2C0%2C6%2C-7%2C9%2C4%2C-2%2C8%2C-8%2C-4%2C1%2C-8%2C4%2C3%2C7%2C3%2C5%2C1%2C0%2C3%2C3%2C7%2C-1%2C-5%2C1%2C-3%2C4%2C-7%2C0%2C3%2C2%2C-2%2C7%2C-3%2C0%2C0%2C2%2C-5%2C8%2C-3%2C-2%2C-7%2C-5%2C7%2C-3%2C-9%2C-7%2C5%2C8%2C-3%2C9%2C6%2C7%2C-2%2C4%2C7%5D&debug=0)

Python 3 translation:

```
print(sorted(eval(input()),key=lambda x:not x))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2.7, <s>31</s> 30 bytes

-1 thanks to dennis

Takes input as array.

```
def f(i):i.sort(key=0..__eq__)
```

Comment: @MuhammadSalman Correct how? The code works, as you can verify in the permalink I left. The function `f` modifies the array in place.

Comment: @Dennis : not that, I know it works, what I meant was whether this comment : "You cannot provide snippet as answer" was correct or not ?

Comment: @MuhammadSalman Yes, [snippets are disallowed by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2423/12012). REPL answers [*are* allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7844/12012), but they still have to adhere to [our defaults for I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/8478).

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 44 bytes

```
{i:List<Int>->i.sortedBy{if(it==0)1 else 0}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVJNb4MwDL3vV1ioBzgEAeEjrUql7TZpO@3aC1qhikZDRbJJFeO3M9spWoPSxs7ze3bsr8H12izdt4FLo03YjGe7g@dxbG77Dzdqcz5EMD0Brp@mh8/B2KHXp8a1UC@T3r1p6/avxh3EQcd2GF17erlNugu1q@skSqHtbQvJPC8rhWuts1BDEARMS@u3gAq2ICGBDL@cTzko9EpI8VRBgf8ZbvLRrtAq@TZDu2BUhlEF7hK3/CcXKYgKRMkoUYDIMFpIEApxCnVTOiKqBJGTQTqCJHOKYuwWgZIwCTNQXgpRKTklRQgSR39CHIqoJOdRICLjj0B3LtaiPAWVndOV4hxynws9AElQwlgKW4JzT4kg90LSkzJnwk@HALXmU5Hl69z6apQX54rokSt@IuxDjI2@vGPrcQCi2F577cLgaIIovjTXe/dpabdewnpHPjfgAIQRzAz0v90whj3OBmjjOx498FxxrlxvwmBDkKPZTA9zxWHRTPJ3vnn5Aw)

### Explanation

```
{ i: List<Int> ->             // lambda taking a List<Int> i
    i.sortedBy {              // sort List by the result of function
        if(it == 0) 1 else 0  // if item is 0 return 1 else 0
    }                         // this will sort i ascending
}                             // while leaving 0s at the end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
ΣĀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVDBDcMwCFyFAWwJ26Q4s1R9pFL36C5dpe@u5GKOuJVMIGfuDsPbcS@PMT6v93OMay6JslpcEm2J5p@lXBNNsFn0RJzIvjuurZok688CpCKpKwi0gr07s4HCIa6OdGcV3DbIzGB0MPQ7nJondger63mc9POKwRgkdUzQ1WN0Wa8Ql8IweDp7DTDHKgrEZU3VlnH4sp@K9v73GAV0LnJfO@pr4NhUdQO9fQE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 29 bytes

```
[ [ sgn abs ] inv-sort-with ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcwxCsIwGEDhvad4F4i0SBD0AOLiIk6lQyyxBmNa/vwoIp49xuXBW76rG3WWcj4djvsteRYNaeLuJfnIw@mNRbzqe5GQlF3TfGjpMJZ1ja3TYjeYjm/p6clTwl0yAyE9zd8zr1CVoYwuRlblBw)

Inverse sort with key function `0 -> 0, not 0 -> 1`.

Comment: Interestingly `[ [ 0 = ] partition prepend ]` has the same byte count.

Comment: @Bubbler Nice. All the same, your solution runs an order of magnitude faster. On an array of 100,000 items on my machine, sorting takes around ~40ms in the listener, but partitioning takes ~4ms.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 3 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ñ¶T
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=8bZU&input=Wy0xIC03IC02IDUgMSAtNSAtMiA3IC0zIC04IDAgOCA5IDEgLTggLTEgNiAtNCAxIC0yIDEgLTcgNSA0IC02IDcgLTMgOSA4IDMgLTEgMCAtNSAtNyAzIDggMSAxIDMgLTMgLTIgLTIgMCAtNyAwIC00IDggNiAtMyA2IDAgNSAzIDIgMiAyIC0yIC03IC0zIDkgLTEgNiAwIDYgLTcgOSA0IC0yIDggLTggLTQgMSAtOCA0IDMgNyAzIDUgMSAwIDMgMyA3IC0xIC01IDEgLTMgNCAtNyAwIDMgMiAtMiA3IC0zIDAgMCAyIC01IDggLTMgLTIgLTcgLTUgNyAtMyAtOSAtNyA1IDggLTMgOSA2IDcgLTIgNCA3XQ)

```
ñ¶T     :Implicit input of array
ñ       :Sort by
 ¶      :Is equal to
  T     :0
```

Answer (score 1):

## Batch 93 bytes

Input is provided as arguments when running the script in windows cmd.exe

```bat
:l
@(Set/A1/%1 2>nul&&Set .=%.%%1 ||set t=%t%%1 )
@If not %1.==. Shift&Goto:l
@Echo %.%%t%
```

Explainer:

```
 @Set/A1/%1                   Attempt to Provoke divide by 0 error
 2>nul                        Redirect STDERR to nul
    &&                        If not 0
      Set .=%.% %1            Append to '.' list
    ||                        Else
      'Set t=%t%%1 '          Append to 't'rail list
 @If not %1.==. Shift&Goto:l  If argument remains, Shift Argument, repeat loop
 @Echo %.%%t%                 Output
```

Note:

```
@     Suppress command Echo
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 10 bytes

```
*.sort(!*)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY1LDoMwDAWv4m4qYFElIcQgPnfpoqxaFQEbTh8GC1mW59l@9vJZvyn/DnnOMubqtf3XvXhUZe5lex8yF4OTRlqipnpJUBSHUnSC401q3LFzORSqoUBEo4hTIX87PBNvvSsVlWwa0I1tBbvk6PNvKvMJ)

An anonymous function that calls `sort` on its argument, where the sort-by function is `!*`, another anonymous function that boolean-inverts its argument.

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com), 19 bytes

```
f(x)=sort(x,0^{xx})
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5vntw8sscg)

Answer (score 1):

## Erlang 86 bytes

```
f(L)->M=lists:filter(fun(E)->E /= 0 end,L),M++lists:duplicate(length(L)-length(M),0).
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <s>36 29</s> 26 bytes

```arturo
$=>[arrange&=>[&0compare]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?CWPIZx)

-7 bytes from Arturo 0.9.83 providing the `arrange` function (higher-order sort).

-3 more by using `compare` over `switch`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 111 bytes, using `golang.org/x/exp/slices`

```go
import."golang.org/x/exp/slices"
func f(I[]int)[]int{SortStableFunc(I,func(a,b int)bool{return b==0});return I}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=nVTLbtNAFN2w8g-wHXk1ljyJn7GT4gULKkXdIGWJUDtOx5aF4zEeB1WK8iVsIiQ-qnwN995xUCkUKBrFvu975hw5n7_U-nT_qpfbD7JWbCebzml2vR7GmVvtRndy2MY149B0tXF_pCGw1d0n9-t-rER-r8_xWreyq2d6qOd3c3XXz03bbBU0Vvtuyyq-fve-6UaPnocNtGxGWbbqErJ87WMRl37JsKbUuj0MatwPHSuLIjh6F5O3Ptq13168pLFX3DCL0OPaLjhUemDXvloVA-BRbDO7bFR7a7jxDo1_vSpej7rhyrvQhex71d1y7TfecdpwdCxeZIR77ODIVXHFbwKWshxODO-QLcBKWABeBv4C7GSyMrKXUIMdGVgxWBGchKwEOjOwwqkjhExIMfxl4C0oG4GfUlVEkwKIw74bzykJjwiZyJhYUJFImYigWcRM5FCWEwAwBUIVCTq4RuDGBLuodkn3EQgVJyCsHKpCDMbYIXA3xAOckeOomGCkUBHRwaJpFu1CmAJvnWAqJwyJxZIQW5Y_ZA49QdhDHJDYRbEdSjMDYk4g8ROeDD17z6W9TW6X042Q4wwYcqQhjn5V7E96ndU6a_U_SqUUC34-qJn5m2jPlexJwXDBA7GeluqfhPq9TA9FerZAj-mZKHJktSoqLoEsMkoIvYXvemw7_ubjXrZcGl9Wns_g8ShTGr_EDDyc6f_hdLLv7w)

## [Go](https://go.dev), 199 bytes, using `sort`

```go
import."sort"
type L[]int
func(l L)Len()int{return len(l)}
func(l L)Less(i,j int)bool{return l[j]==0}
func(l L)Swap(i,j int){l[i],l[j]=l[j],l[i]}
func f(I[]int)[]int{l:=L(I);Stable(l);return[]int(l)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=nVTNbtpAEL705DfobcVpV_KCDQYbkA89tFIUDpU4IpqsiW05NbbrNW0qiyfpBVXqs_QZ0qfpzKxBpGnaplqxzM83M9_OJ_jyNS0P9-8qtXmv0phtVVZY2bYq66bfS7ZN7-Tops6KVD8IbMri4zHAlqyXlrkq0n5Zp4O7QXxXDXSebWLd-7ZrEhncfz-Vwt2zms9VzBardVY0VrIrNjxnC7GICy4g0tZxs6sLloOfi_05QGue2bcMQCIqy_yEXN2uw9A5gy4_qeoEbfNVtrYJhJeNrsGyhF8QC0F3m8_CBb8Q82WjojyG6XMzgbJIxjznx4uXVH3JNTPLEbw0fdqkrNmVHc_CGvYRszdZnN9orkWb2Vez8FVTZjwW8zJUVRUXN7y0M7HvpuwtQwqV4IK1lpqFl_zaYWMWwBnBt8smYHnMAc8HfwK211k-2VPAYIUP1gisIRyPLA8qfbDcrsKFjEsx_PjgTSg7BH9MqCF1ciAO866FFREf6TLpMzkhkBwzOYRiOWIyAFhABMCUSFV66OAYiRM9rCLslN4jkSp2QFoBoFwMjrBC4myIO9gjwFYjojEGxJAOgrpeNAtpSny1h6mAOHiGi0fbMvvDzaEnibuLDTwzaGSaUk-HNidx8R0fHz3zzql5TWCG04twxz5syFKadvRYsT_pdVTrqNX_KDWmmPPwoGb6b6I9V7InBcMBZ2I9LdU_CfV7mc5FerZAv66nW5GlklmYcAXLIiOC0Fv4VTd5wZf91x92KudK2yoRNoPrUS7SdoQ5uKzuH-JwMN8_AQ)

Answer (score 1):

### F#, 28 bytes

Based on the answers that use booleans:

```
let s=Seq.sortBy(fun x->x=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZK9CoMwFIX3PEUQCjpYEo2mHXToK3QsnSRCQJI2ScFC391WB4VyCGa4HJJ85/5we5931qlpGlSgvrmq59FbFy7vtH8ZOubt2LBseezsMKguaGtoQ@jv3JY4H7aqalUnoErwj6@qBoQAOTYXCfxqwIqdhIyyZ1Az6lwCogREAZSIEgJMSAKC7@ycgwp4NAe6k8CljlZVAL8qWn0RnTgDef/35U7ItsHk01I/h3nfdVCOpg@nTegNTQ46yQhh0xc)

Another longer, but possibly more interesting way, is to use `Seq.mapFold` for **120 bytes**:

```
let m=Seq.mapFold(fun c n->if n=0 then None,c+1 else Some n,c)0>>fun(i,c)->Seq.concat[Seq.choose id i;Seq.replicate c 0]
```

which counts and strips out the zeros from the collection, then appends that number of zeros at the end of the collection.

[Try this online too!](https://tio.run/##jVKxasMwEN31FUeg4NC4SI5jJQRr7NglY8gQlDMRyJLrqFv/3ZU8OFAOEQ3Hk3Tv3bvjukep/YjTZDFA357w@6O/Dp/e3orux4EGVyrTgWs5hDs6@PION/pdANoHwsn3CG6j11ypmF6YCEuVRLR3@hrOM7x7H3PNDcwx3UccrImfGNX5ZS6svbWog/EOWgbxnOeYDl/QbkF7Am2JPLGghmDURI2niiT0GoJbv8iQWe6B8Ex1LgnGlmBUBKqzjJqYkCQY4sXOBeFAZGtQb5JQabKuKkJvl3VfZSfOibr/9@XC2HOD2a@CPoW06ybgCMUwGhc6B6s3s1ozxqc/)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy), 18 bytes

```
lDv\[}D(X]lv-i*\0r

l                  Get length of stack
 Dv                Duplicate and grab for later
   \[    ]         Do everything in the loop that many times.
     }             Rotate the stack right.
      D(X          If the item is 0, delete it.
          lv-i*    Get the value of original length - current length.
               \0  Push that many zeroes.
                 r Reverse the stack.
```

This leaves the sorted array on the stack.

** Note that this no longer works for the current version! **

Answer (score 0):

## GNU Sed, 25

Score includes +1 for use of `-E` option.

(Almost) direct port of [my Retina answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70807/11259):

```
:
s/\b0 ([^0].*)/\1 0/
t
```

Comment: Only GNU `sed` versions from before [this commit](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-sed/2015-08/txtV5HUjkXYBN.txt) ([discussion](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-sed/2015-08/msg00002.html))

Comment: @sch Dammit - that adds 2 bytes to lots of my sed answers :(

Answer (score 0):

## `sed`, 16 bytes

```
$G
/[^0]/b
G
h
d
```

it expects a newline delimited stdin input array

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, <s>77</s> <s>64</s> 62 bytes

```
DEF C A
DIM B[LEN(A)]ARYOP 2,B,A,A
ARYOP 6,B,B,2,1SORT B,A
END
```

Modifies input array in-place.

### Explanation

```
DEF CONSOLIDATE ARRAY
 DIM B[LEN(ARRAY)] 'create another array of the same length
 ARYOP #AOPMUL,B,ARRAY,ARRAY 'square each element in ARRAY and store the result in B
 ARYOP #AOPCLP,B,B,2,1 'clamp each element in B to be "between" 2 (min) and 1 (max)
 SORT B,ARRAY 'sort A and B, using B
END
```

`ARYOP` is a function that does simple operations to entire arrays at once.

My goal is to convert all `0`s into one value, and every other number into another value. It is important that `0` turns into a HIGHER value than the other numbers, so they will be placed at the end during sorting.

(It would be simpler to convert non-zero numbers to `1`, and leave `0` unchanged, but this doesn't work. There is a `RSORT` function, but it actually just sorts the array and reverses it, so it would not leave the order of other numbers unchanged.)

First, the negative numbers need to be made positive. The simplest way to do this is by squaring them. The result is stored in `B`.

Next, these values are clamped into the range `[2,1]`. Technically this is an invalid range, but it works due to the way clamping is implemented.

```
if (number >= start)
   number = start
else if (number <= end)
   number = end
```

Notice that it checks `>=` rather than `>`, and that if the first check happens, the second is skipped.

For example:
`0` is not greater than or equal to `1`, but it is smaller than `2`, so it is set to `2`.
`1` IS greater than or equal to `1`, so it is set to `1`.
(The second check is skipped, even though `1` is smaller than `2`)
`2` is greater than or equal to `1`, so it is set to `1`.
etc.

#### So now, we have converted all `0`s into `2`s, and every other number into a `1`.

We can now use `SORT` to sort the input array by our modified array. This will put all the `0`s at the end, and leave the nonzero numbers in the same order (`SORT` uses a stable sorting algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 2 bytes

```
Ö¬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3dDUBQDEZXuSPcP7fsYA4h4knEM0OYwhRsYpE6Gmmanq/t1/bLPOqzb9PQtavex3WqqneVq4lEDa5A2XmUoAucfxLjhp3PIVCCIpGNMk6Bwu8ITIL1vhRUsWlEV7YV7ZKnz78X)

order by negation.