# Help me do my washing

Tags: code-golf, array, sorting

Help! My **[Completely Automated Lights From Darks Separator V3001.01](http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTEyWDUxMg==/z/E1MAAOSwr81UPxrD/$_1.JPG)** broke! :(

## Guidelines

---

### Task

Write a program that will take an input of an array (or a list in some languages) of any amount of strings that are either the letter L or the letter  D (representing lights or darks) and output an array that contains two arrays, one with all the L's, and one with all the D's.

---

### Rules

- It's code golf so the shortest answer in bytes wins
- Input will only ever contain capitals
- There must be the same number of L's in the output as there is in the input, same goes for the D's
- The input may only have one element (or maybe even *zero* elements)
- If one or both of the output arrays contain no elements, output an empty list (in some languages this may mean you need to output a string)
- Always have the first array be the array of L's

---

### Example output:

`["L","D","L","D","D"] -> [["L","L"],["D","D","D"]]`

`["L","L","L"] -> [["L","L","L"],[]]`

`["D","D"] -> [[],["D","D"]]`

`[] -> [[],[]]`

Comment: Can we input/output as a string? For example: `"LDLDD" -> "LL DDD"` or something  like that?

Comment: Or output perhaps as a list of the two strings, e.g. `"LDLDD" -> ["LL", "DDD"]

Comment: Would also like an answer, as my answer depends on this

Comment: How about mixed output? As in an array containing one string and one array of strings? e.g., `["L","L",["D","D","D"]]`.

Comment: No, the output must be an array/list. @ComradeSparklePony

Comment: Is it acceptable to take a string as input e.g. `'LDLDD'` instead of `['L', 'D', 'L', 'D', 'D']`?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer No the input must be an array/list. However, I would presume in most languages it would be easy to convert an array of string to a string?

Comment: @Amorris Yeah it should probably.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer After all, a string is an array of characters...

Comment: Welp, that's braingolf out then. Can't do nested arrays

Comment: @Amorris what about 2 separate Arrays (IE `[L, L], [D, D, D]`) as opposed to an array of arrays?

Comment: @Mayube Sure thats fine, not sure how your gonna get that in one output though...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## APL, 8 bytes

```
'DL'~⍨¨⊂
```

Explanation:

- `⊂`: enclosed input
- `~⍨¨`: without each
- `'DL'`: 'D' and 'L'

Examples:

```
      ('DL'~⍨¨⊂) 'LDLDD'
┌──┬───┐
│LL│DDD│
└──┴───┘
      ('DL'~⍨¨⊂) 'LLL'
┌───┬┐
│LLL││
└───┴┘
      ('DL'~⍨¨⊂) 'DD'
┌┬──┐
││DD│
└┴──┘
      ('DL'~⍨¨⊂) ''
┌┬┐
│││
└┴┘
```

Comment: Why is it `'DL'` but not `'LD'`?

Comment: @LeakyNun: added explanation. It works by removing the wrong character rather than selecting the right one.

Comment: `'LD'∩⍨¨⊂` or `⍞∘∩¨'LD'` may be easier to explain.

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 37 bytes

```python
lambda a:[[c]*a.count(c)for c in"LD"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHRKjo6OVYrUS85vzSvRCNZMy2/SCFZITNPycdFKfZ/QVEmUDRNI1rJR0lHyQWIYTRQVlOTC1UeglHFsagFcv4DAA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 28 bytes

```hs
f l=[filter(==[c])l|c<-"LD"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hxzY6LTOnJLVIw9Y2OjlWM6cm2UZXycdFKfZ/iW10tJKPko6SCxDDaKCEDkQUgkE8uHhsLFduYmaegq1CbmKBr4JGQWlJcEmRT55ecUZ@uaaCCkhYIU2h5D8A)

If the input can be a list of characters, the `[]` around `c` can be removed.

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 46 bytes

Assumed given list is:
`$arr = ['L','L','D','D','L','D','D','D','D','L'];`

`foreach($arr as $b){$a[$b][]=$b;};print_r($a);`

Comment: As a default I/O rule, you cannot assume input is stored in one variable

Comment: @KeyuGan argh! Fair enough

Comment: Use can use `$argv` instead of `$arr` and expect the script to be run from command line as `php -f golf.php L L D D L D D D D L` - but then again you have to go around $argv[0] which is the file name

Comment: using this way the shortest solutions are `for(;$b=$argv[++$i];)$a[$b][]=$b;print_r($a);` or `<?foreach($_GET as$b)$a[$b][]=$b;print_r($a);`

Comment: My first golf attempt after years lurking and I'm still a total amateur! Thanks for the feedback (and up-votes) though everyone :)!

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 27 bytes

```
Rest/@Gather[{L,D}~Join~#]&
```

Pure function taking a list of `L`s and `D`s (symbols, not characters/strings) as input and returning a list of two lists. For example,

```
Rest/@Gather[{L,D}~Join~#]& @ {D, L, L, D, L}
```

returns `{{L, L, L}, {D, D}}`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvs/KLW4RN/BHSiQWhRd7aPjUlvnlZ@ZV6ccq/Y/oCgzryQ6zaHaRUfBB4xAjNrY/wA)

`Gather` by itself is close to what we want, but fails to meet the spec in two ways: it doesn't produce empty lists if the input is missing `L`s or `D`s, and it doesn't always sort `L`s to the left. Replacing the input `#` with `{L,D}~Join~#` solves both problems at once: it means there will be at least one `L` and at least one `D`, and the `L`s will be returned first since an `L` was encountered first. `Rest/@` then removes the initial `L` and `D`.

(I tried a solution using `Count`, but due to currying issues, it didn't seem to be shorter: `±q_:=#~Table~Count[q,#]&/@{L,D}` is 31 bytes.)

Comment: TIO link (mathics)?

Comment: How about `Cases@@@{{#,L},{#,D}}&`, for 22 bytes?

Comment: Great idea, Not a tree! You should post that answer—I'll upvote :)

Comment: [Done!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132059/66104)

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 32 bytes

```
import Data.List
partition(>"K")
```

Just a boring library function.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRMElsSRRzyezuIQrzbYgsagksyQzP0/DTslbSfN/bmJmnoKtQko@l4JCQVFmXomCikKaQrSSj5KOkgsQw2gXpVgsKiA4VgFNCqoBTTj2PwA)

Comment: Try with no imports :P

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>13</s> <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
2Æf¥"LD"gX
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=MsZmpSJMRCJnWA==&input=WyJMIiwiRCIsIkwiLCJEIiwiRCJdCi1R) (`-Q` flag for visualisation purposes only)

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of array `U`.

```
2Æ
```

Generate the array `[0,1]` and pass each element through a function, with `X` being the current element.

```
f¥
```

Filter `U` by checking for equality...

```
"LD"gX
```

...with the character in string `LD` at index `X`.

Comment: "Hmm, removing the `¥` should work..." `[["L","L","D","D"],[]]` "Nope, not going there :)" - me 2017

Comment: @ETHproductions: Ha-ha! Yeah, I tried so many ways to try to get it to work without the `¥`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 26 bytes

```ruby
->x{x.partition{|e|e==?L}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf166iukKvILGoJLMkMz@vuia1JtXW1t6ntvZ/QWlJsUJadLSSj5KOkgsQw2gXpdhYBVtbBaiUj1KsTjRUAiLJhaIVqgZVC1QbUC1CMarZCEORFSHJAoX/AwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), <strike>42</strike>, 37 bytes

```
l('L').
w(L,D,W):-partition(l,W,L,D).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/P0cjQtNKN8JW3Uddj6tcw0fHRSccKFCQWFSSWZKZn6eRoxOuAxTV1Pv/v1zDUcdJJxqoVAeMXeB0rKYeAA)

Given that `W` is a list of washing, `w/3` will unify `L` and `D` into lists of Lights and Darks respectively, by partitioning the washing against a predicate which succeeds if an item is a Light.

[Edit: golfed -5 thanks to [Fatalize](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41723/fatalize)]

Comment: `l('L').` is 5 bytes shorter than `l(X):-X='L'.`

Comment: @Fatalize - thanks! Edited in.

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, <s>66</s> 65 bytes

```
(defun f(x)`(,(remove"D"x :test'equal),(remove"L"x :test'equal)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74/18jJTWtNE8hTaNCM0FDR6MoNTe/LFXJRalCwaoktbhEPbWwNDFHEy7hgyahqflfo6AoM69EQSNNQV0DqFEBjH2QaAgGKQUA)

If, instead of strings, we use symbols, then it is much shorter:

## Common Lisp, <s>42</s> <s>41</s> 40 bytes

```
(defun f(x)(mapcar'remove'(D L)`(,x,x)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DclLCsAgDAXAq2SXF/AYLj2EYhWEasV@yO1TmeXks93TDEep76AKFfQ0c1q8Sr@@wvAUJMKpUxExzNXGQ6jECOS3sH/HDw)

```
(f '(D D L L D L D)) ; => ((L L L) (D D D D))
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP7, <s>52</s> 45 bytes

*-7 bytes thanks to @Jörg Hülsermann*

```
foreach($argv as$a)$$a[]=$a;print_r([$L,$D]);
```

Use with CLI as `php -r a.php L L L D D L D`

The script goes through the provided arguments and appends them to an array based on its value.

Comment: 45 bytes with using `-r` option instead of `-f` remove`<?php` and drop the space after the `as`

Answer (score 2):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org), 48 bytes

```
(compose list((curry partition)(λ(x)(eq? x'L))))
```

Just apply this anonymous function to, e.g., `'(L D L D D L)`

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, <s>22</s> 18 bytes

*4 bytes saved by the genius of CalculatorFeline!*

```
Cases@@@{#|L,#|D}&
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvvfObE4tdjBwaFaucZHR7nGpVbtf0BRZl6JQ5pDtYuOi44PBNf@BwA), or at the [Wolfram sandbox](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/)!

Input is a list of the symbols `L` and `D` — not strings, just the letters on their own, like in [Greg Martin's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/131835/66104). The syntax `#|L` is shorthand for `Alternatives[#,L]`, but the `@@@` syntax replaces the head `Alternatives` with `Cases`, so this code is equivalent to `{Cases[#,L],Cases[#,D]}&`.

Comment: `{#,x}` can be `#|x` for -4 bytes.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline, wow, that trick is amazing! Thank you!

Comment: `@@` and `@@@` work with any head, not just `List`. If `|` doesn't work, you can still save in some cases with `&&`, `||`, or `**`.

Comment: You can also use `.` and arithmetic operators.

Comment: Also, precedence abuse has more savings for you (with an output format change): `#.L|#.D`

Comment: @CalculatorFeline, I can't get that to work without brackets, and `Cases@@@(#.L|#.D)&` is no shorter than the current answer. What version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot about that X(

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
mc@dQ1"LD
```

[Test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=mc%40dQ1%22LD&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%22L%22%2C%22D%22%2C%22L%22%2C%22D%22%2C%22D%22%5D%0A%5B%22L%22%2C%22L%22%2C%22L%22%5D%0A%5B%22D%22%2C%22D%22%5D%0A%5B%5D&debug=0).

Comment: Using `.g` seems to be [shorter](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=>2%2B%2CYY.g&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B"L"%2C"D"%2C"L"%2C"D"%2C"D"%5D%0A%5B"L"%2C"L"%2C"L"%5D%0A%5B"D"%2C"D"%5D%0A%5B%5D&debug=0).

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
'LÃ¹'DÃ)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9f3edw86Gd6i6HmzX//49W8lHSgeJYAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ES6), 37 bytes

This is based on a (now deleted) Javascript (ES6) answer.

```js
a=>[(b=c=>a.filter(d=>c==d))`L`,b`D`]
```

**Ungolfed version:**

```js
function(array) {
  function filter(character){
    return array.filter(function(d) {
      return character == d;
    });
  }
  return [filter("L"), filter("D")];
}
```

**Example code snippet:**

```js
f=

a=>[(b=c=>a.filter(d=>c==d))`L`,b`D`]

console.log(f(["L", "D", "L", "D", "D"]))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>110</s> 106 bytes

```java
a->{String[]r={"",""};for(char c:a)r[c/69]+=c;return new char[][]{r[1].toCharArray(),r[0].toCharArray()};}
```

-4 bytes thanks to *@Nevay*.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##rZBNT8MwDIbv/RVWL01FF@CCBFEnIXaEXcYt6iGkGUtpk8pNh6Yqv71k7cYkrkNKLH/otR@7EnuxsK0yVfk16qa16KAKOdo7XdNnRHHoWCRr0XXwJrQZIgBtnMKtkArWxxBA7gTyghcgyeyCSFmo@PDD65xwWsIaDOQwisVy2DjU5pMXmA9xnMWxZ1uLkxbkk0iRy9uHx@ImlwyV69GAUd@/Uwbk9wV19iXEEyBJM@R3f1Ke@ZHN89v@ow7zTxh7q0towirkTBFo5z02h86phtre0TaUXG3IfAFaKtW@21lADJXkAjQkr0kGyepoLt4q8Wk6HeG6tidzdbN/gjrrfeTHHw)

```java
a->{                      // Method with char-array parameter and 2D char-array return-type
  String[]r={"",""};      //  Two Strings in an array
  for(char c:a)           //  Loop over the characters of the input
    r[c/69]+=c;           //   Append either of the two String with the character
                          //   c/69 will result in 0 for 'D' and 1 for 'L'
                          //  End of loop (implicit / single-line body)
  return new char[][]{    //  Return a 2D character-array
    r[1].toCharArray(),   //   With the String for L's converted to a char-array
    r[0].toCharArray()};  //   and String D's converted to a char-array
}                         // End of method
```

Comment: You can store l and d in an array to remove the if-else statement. `a->{String[]r={"",""};for(char c:a)r[c/69]+=c;return new char[][]{r[1].toCharArray(),r[0].toCharArray()};}` (-4 bytes)

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 61 bytes

```c#
using System.Linq;a=>new[]{a.Where(c=>c<69),a.Where(c=>c>68)}
```

Full/Formatted Version:

```c#
using System;
using System.Linq;

class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Func<char[], System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<char>[]> f =
            a => new[] { a.Where(c => c < 69), a.Where(c => c > 68) };

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", f(new[]{ 'L', 'D', 'L', 'D', 'D' }).SelectMany(a => a.Select(c => c))));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [F#](http://fsharp.org/), 37 bytes

```fs
let f s=List.partition(fun a->a="L")s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWzc3Py///Pye1RCFNodjWJ7O4RK8gsagksyQzP08jrTRPIVHXLtFWyUdJs/h/QVFmXklanoKSqqOSgkaaQjRQ2FrJBYhhtItSrCYXdmUQjFUat85Yzf8A)

Takes input as a list of strings, and returns two lists, the first with elements where `fun a -> a="L"` is true and the other with elements that result in false.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
ẎfÐ€⁾LDW€€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrr60wxMeNa151LjPxyUcxGha8/9w@9FJD3fO@P8/Wt1HXUdB3QVEIFgu6rEA)

In Jelly a string is a list of 1-char Python strings, e.g. `['a', 'b', 'c']`. That's why you get output such as `[[['L'], ['L']], [['D'], ['D'], ['D']]]`, since 1-char Jelly strings behave the same.

Doesn't work as a full program, hence the `ÇŒṘ` at the bottom.

Comment: @Leo Hmm, you may be right...fixed.

Comment: It seems Jelly input is different from Jelly output?  Does the interpreter do `string->char[]` automagically?

Comment: @nmjcman101 On strings it's different, since input is in Python format and output is in Jelly format. That's why I need the `W€€` part.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perse](https://github.com/faso/Perse), 21 bytes

```
part(i,fn(x){x=="L"})
```

I may or may not have implemented the list partition function specifically for this challenge. Takes the input as an array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
Mof-"DL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fq1EcrPOoqfG/b36arpKLz////6OjlXyUdJRcgBhGuyjF6kBEIRjEg4vHxgIA)

#### Explanation

```
Mof-"DL
M   "DL    For each character in ['D','L']:
 of-         keep only those strings that are not empty if that character is removed
```

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 21 bytes

```
@(A){A(a=A>72),A(~a)}
```

Input is an array of characters, output is a cell array. Recycled from my answer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/70779/consolidate-an-array/70827#70827).

Sample execution on [ideone](https://ideone.com/akbaAJ).

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 35 bytes

```r
x=scan(,'');list(x[i<-x>'D'],x[!i])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8K2ODkxT0NHXV3TOiezuESjIjrTRrfCTt1FPVanIloxM1bzv4@Cj4ILEILJ/wA)

Reads from stdin.

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 26 bytes

```julia
g(s)=s[s.=="L"],s[s.=="D"]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 20 bytes

```ruby
->l{[l-[?D],l-[?L]]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6nOjpHN9reJVYHRPnExtb@L1BIi45W8lHSUXIBYhjtohQby4WQgmC4EKoKIP0fAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
`LDdẊcx×
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#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)

##### Explanation

```python
`LDdẊcx×  # Implicit input                   ->  ["L","D","L","D","D"]
`LD       # Push the string "LD"             ->  ["L","D","L","D","D"]  "LD"
   d      # Split it into characters         ->  ["L","D","L","D","D"]  ["L","D"]
    Ẋ     # Store it in x without popping    ->  ["L","D","L","D","D"]  ["L","D"]
     c    # Count occurrences in the input   ->  [2,3]
      x×  # Multiply by x elementwise        ->  [["L","L"],["D","D","D"]]
          # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) (Lambdabot), 41 bytes

```hs
reverse.map tail.group.sort.("LD"++).join
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY29DoIwGEX3PsWXskCAvgEDAcNSDIsTEtPEotXSNm11MT57rT8MDic3uecm98zclUsZHmUCtN52u7rbQDMMkJRPJBajrYdGK2@1JL1W7LiWLfOMUOE8mqt9sPzOreNkYQY8E5KcrL4Z4uKSpJi2OM8zctFCBc@dd1AhgBFGTHGB28iaLZ6iKX7my9r8@XdMCC1MKKgg3vYHSI0VypM5g89JeAE)

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 27 bytes

```powershell
($args-eq'L'),($args-eq'D')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0MlsSi9WDe1UN1HXVMHwXNR1/z//7@Pgo@CCwgDAA)

---

Edit: previously `$args.where({$_-eq'L'},'sp')` for 28 bytes. Could be `$args.where({+"0x$_"},'sp')` for 27 if not for the rule that L's must come first.

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>21</s> 11 bytes

-10 bytes thanks to [CalculatorFeline](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/51443/calculatorfeline)

```
O^`.
LD
L D
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/fPy5Bj8vHhctHweX/fx8XHxcXAA)

Comment: The 21 byte version can be `O^\`.` `LD` `L D`.

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 14 bytes

```
"LD"qf{1$e=*}`
```

Input is a list of characters (string), output is a list of lists of characters (list of strings).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/X8nHRakwrdpQJdVWqzbh/38fIHABAiDp4wIA)

Explanation:

```
"LD"  e# Push the string "LD"                  | "LD"
q     e# Push the input                        | "LD" "LDLLDLDDL"
f{    e# Foreach char in "LD", push input and: | ['L "LDLLDLDDL"
  1$  e#   Copy from 1 back                    | ['L "LDLLDLDDL" 'L
  e=  e#   Count occurences                    | ['L 5
  *   e#   Repeat character                    | ["LLLLL"
}     e# End                                   | ["LLLLL" "DDDD"]
`     e# Stringify:                            | "[\"LLLLL\" \"DDDD\"]"
e# Implicit output: ["LLLLL" "DDDD"]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 70 bytes

```perl
$"='","';@L=(L)x y/L//;@D=(D)x y/D//;$_="[[\"@L\"],[\"@D\"]]";s/""//g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19FyVZdSUdJ3drBx1bDR7NCoVLfR1/f2sHFVsMFzHMB8lTibZWio2OUHHxilGJ1QAwXICNWybpYX0lJXz/9///o2H/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA3@6xYAAA)

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript, 38 bytes

```
q=>['L','D'].map(x=>q.filter(y=>x==y))
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! We do not allow answers that assume a variable as input, we call these snippets.  Instead format your answer as a function (named on unnamed), or a full program with IO.

Comment: Thanks @FunkyComputerMan. I edited it, let me know if it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 13 bytes

```
<@-."1 0&'DL'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/38dWT8HGQVdPyVDBQE3dxUf9f2pyRr6Dj7VevJFCcUlKZp66@n8XFxcfHxDi8vHx4eJy4QIA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 53 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 6.625 bytes

```
‛LDƛ?Oẋf
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9IiwiIiwi4oCbTETGmz9P4bqLZiIsIiIsIltcIkxcIiwgXCJMXCJdIl0=)

Ports Thonnu 2

### Explained

```
‛LDƛ?Oẋf­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
‛LDƛ      # ‎⁡To each character in the string "LD":
    ?O    # ‎⁢  Count the character in the input
      ẋ   # ‎⁣  And list repeat it that many times
       f  # ‎⁤  flatten that
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).