# Am I a Special N-bonacci Number?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, fibonacci

The N-bonacci sequence, originally invented by @DJMcMayhem in [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/70476/61613), is a sequence generated by starting with the integers 0 and 1, and then adding the previous N numbers to generate the next number.  The special N-bonacci sequence is an N-bonacci sequence beginning with a pair of numbers other than 0 and 1, which will be named X and Y.  If N is greater than the number of terms already in the sequence, simply add all available terms.

So for example the normal fibonacci sequence has an N of 2 (takes the previous two items), and an X and Y of 0 and 1, or 1 and 1, depending on who you ask.

### Your Task:

You are to write a program or function that checks whether an inputted integer (A) is part of the special N-bonacci sequence generated by the next three integers (using the second input as N, and the third and fourth as X and Y).  Ensure that you handle the special case of N=1.

### Input:

Four non-negative integers, A, N, X, and Y.

### Output:

A truthy/falsy value that indicates whether A is part of the N-bonacci sequence generated by the N, X, and Y inputs.

### Test Cases:

```
Input:    Output:
13,2,0,1->truthy
12,3,1,4->falsy
4,5,0,1-->truthy
8,1,8,9-->truthy
9,1,8,9-->truthy

12,5,0,1->falsy  [0,1]>[0,1,1]>[0,1,1,2]>[0,1,1,2,4]>[0,1,1,2,4,8]>[0,1,1,2,4,8,16]>etc.
```

### Scoring:

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the lowest score in bytes wins.

Comment: `N==1` is such a weird case.

Comment: Yep, but weird cases are what makes this fun :)

Comment: If you do indeed want answers to handle the case `N=1`, you might want to call it out in the question, since many answers (including all current answers, I think) will have a failure condition that assumes a strictly increasing series. Also, can `X` and `Y` be negative? That will probably also  invalidate all existing answers.

Comment: No, X and Y are "non-negative integers" (in the question, under input).  N=1 has been edited into the question.

Comment: I think all existing answers fail to handle the non-increasing case where both X and Y are zero. Is it necessary to handle that case as well?

Comment: I think you should add the truthy cases `8,1,8,9` and `9,1,8,9` to ensure that `N=1` case handling detects the non-repeated `X` value as well as the `Y` value. (If you want to handle `0,0` cases you should add that as well.)

Comment: Test case which I suspect very few answers get right: `2,1,1,0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ḣ⁴S;µṀ<⁵µ¿⁵e
```

A full program taking `[X,Y]`, `N`, `A`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjsWPGrcEWx/a@nBng82jxq2Hth7aD6RS////H22oYxL73/i/oREA)**

#### How?

```
ḣ⁴S;µṀ<⁵µ¿⁵e - Main link (monadic): [X,Y]
    µ   µ¿   - while:
     Ṁ       -   maximum value of the list
       ⁵     -   5th command line argument (3rd input) = A
      <      -   less than?
             - ...do:
 ⁴           -   4th command line argument (2nd input) = N
ḣ            -   head (get the first N (or less) items from the list)
  S          -   sum
   ;         -   concatenate (add the result to the front of the list)
          ⁵  - 5th command line argument (3rd input) = A
           e - exists in the resulting list?
```

Comment: Excellent.  Seems to work for me, anyway.  +1

Comment: To instead see the reversed N-bonacci sequence up to a value greater than or equal to A just remove the `⁵e` from the end; much easier to tell it will work then (noting that the order of the first two terms is of no consequence).

Comment: Tried a bunch of test cases, so unless someone finds one it fails, it's good with me.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 18 bytes

```
[DR²£O©‚˜³®>‹#]³QZ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/2iXo0KZDi/0PrXzUMOv0nEObD62ze9SwUzn20ObAKKC0oY5hLJcRl@XXvHzd5MTkjFQA)

---

Uses: `[X,Y], N, A`

---

I feel like some unintended functionality made that harder than it needed to be.

There's no greater-than-or-equal-to, never noticed that before.

And `#³` didn't work, and required a `]`, for +1 bytes `#]³`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>59</s> 56 bytes

```python
a,n,l=input()
while l[0]<a:l=[sum(l[:n])]+l
print a in l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYtBCsMgEADvvkI8Kd1DNOlF6ksWD1KECNutVEPb19sEWuhxmJn67uud3WhBKTUSMFAoXLeujXiuhbIknOIleQrYtpsm9BxNPJGoj8JdJllY0tjnb259fuWrbmagncEBWphiFGgdzIAL2AMWOP@LH3wA)

Takes input as `A,N,[X,Y]`

Comment: [Here](https://tio.run/##TcvBCgIhEIDhu08RnpRmoXG3i6xPMsxBQljBTNKl9ulto4KOHz9/2dpyy6ZXJ6XsHjIkF3NZm9LiscQUDokG5NnbdHRU16vanS1rFuUec/tk53zf/@@BNjzDRVXdCUcwQCdAZkFoYARCmN6Y4PwffngB) is a wrapper for all test cases if you like it.

Comment: [Here](https://tio.run/##TYtNCwIhEEDv/orwpDSH1d0u0vySwYOEsMI0SbpUv94@KOj4eO/VR18v4kdDrfVIIMBYpG7dWHVbC@cd0xSPKTBS286GKUi0cc@qXov0j0VM43V/exfyPZ9Ms4PcDB7IwRSjIudhBlrAvWGBw7/4wRM) are 2 bytes golfed off.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 47 bytes

```perl6
->\A,\N,\X,\Y{A∈(X,Y,{[+] @_.tail(N)}...*>A)}
```

[test it](https://tio.run/##TY9NboNADIX3cwovqjITzKQkaRaNIHCBrLpIVKqKMpMUiZ8RDFVRSta5S2/Ro@QiFAJqu7Hs58/PtpJFsmyrUsL7kkcrktZwG@VCgtNabuBjsMFgi8Hu6F/OZ7rFHR6fzGfwXrgO44RuWMM5n7g@a9pu1NOy1OBAEmeypIwfCqnoesJ4GqqHIwEwv794lKevdBoIc8oQ1l2ZdVZZSQ1dVPqtNhhpiBCD14r0pz1eM5WEGZijvM@LcZvlAgUvzlSlEW7kh5KRlgIY9Pvi0hJSqqSG/in6OXDsH4jjLD/EndkJDHDcLpz@CNK09hxneIe25Q43EnuGc7RxYbn7MClrssD7a/8X6IlBGogf)

### Expanded:

```perl6
->
  \A,
  \N,
  \X, \Y
{
    A          # is ｢A｣

  ∈            # an element of

    (          # this Sequence

      X, Y,        # seed values of sequence

      {            # generate the rest of the Seq using this code block

        [+]        # reduce by addition

          @_       # of all previously generated values
          .tail(N) # only use the last ｢N｣ of them
      }

      ...          # keep generating values until

      * > A        # it is greater than ｢A｣

    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 50 bytes

```python
a,n,l=input()
while[a]>l:l=[sum(l[:n])]+l
a in l>x
```

Takes input as `A,N,[Y,X]`. Outputs via exit code.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcvRCoMgFIDhe5/i0JWyc5HVbhz1IiJDwi3hzMSM6uldg2B3Px/88cjTHJqy9FVVFYsBqfchrpkLtk2enLZmIEW9XtYPJ62CEeZGzIIPQMNezo295gTPHyQb3o53QjGAnA4FbncjX8QDYvIhQ32620cXs7pEFtlig1pibZhssEXdoTSsw/sfr/wC)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>69</s> 60 bytes

```r
function(a,n,l){while(l<a)l=c(sum(l[1:n],na.rm=T),l)
a%in%l}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jUSdPJ0ezujwjMydVI8cmUTPHNlmjuDRXIyfa0CovVicvUa8o1zZEE6iIK1E1M081p/Z/moahsY6RTrKGgY6hpuZ/AA)

Returns an anonymous function, taking `a,n` and a vector `l=c(y,x)`. Constructs the N-bonacci sequence backwards (i.e., smaller index is further in the sequence), since `while(l<a)` only checks the first element of `l`.

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 164 bytes

```
(defun f(a n x y &aux(l(list y x)))(if(= n 1)(or(= a x)(= a y))(loop(if(<= a(car l))(return(member a l))(setf l(cons(reduce'+ l)(if(<(length l)n)l(butlast l))))))))
```

This function returns `NIL` for false, non-NIL for true (according to the definition of *generalized boolean* of Common Lisp).

```
(defun f(a n x y &aux (l (list y x)))    ; initialize a list l for the N values
  (if (= n 1)                            ; special case for N = 1
      (or (= a x) (= a y))               ;    true only if A = X or A = Y
      (loop
        (if (<= a (car l))               ; when the last number generated is greater than A
            (return (member a l))        ; return true if A is in the list
            (setf l (cons (reduce '+ l)  ; otherwise compute the sum of l
                          (if (< (length l) n)   ; and push it to l (truncating the list at 
                              l                  ; end if it has already size = N)
                              (butlast l))))))))
```

Comment: Does you special-case handling for `N=1` detect an `A` of, e.g., both `1` and/or `2` when `X=1 Y=2`? My Lisp-reading skills are not great, but it looks like you might only compare `A` to one of the two initial values.

Comment: @apsillers , when N=1 I compare A only with X and not with Y. should I compare it with both returning true if it is equal to one of them? Maybe the sequence is not well defined for this case?

Comment: Ok, now I see the question has been changed, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

## k, 29 bytes

```
{x=*(*x>){(x=#y)_y,+/y}[y]/z}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qusJWS0Orwk6zWqPCVrlSM75SR1u/sja6Mla/qvZ/mp66hoahsbWRtYGCoaa1hqGRtbG1oYIJkGlibQoVtABKGyoYaGr@BwA) `1` is truthy, `0` is falsey. Input is `[A;N;X,Y]`.

Comment: I ran it on all examples that I saw. 1 is truthy, 0 is falsey.

Comment: @Gryphon I moved the input over to the footer instead of the body, but I'm not certain what you want me to change. It both is and was the same function.

Comment: Oh, I see now.  I thought you weren't taking any input, but you were taking it in the code.  Makes much more sense now.  I don't know k, so I assumed you'd missinterpreted the question, as all it would do was output 1 0 1 1

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 94 bytes

```
(s={#3,#4};t=1;While[t<#2-1,s~AppendTo~Tr@s;t++];!LinearRecurrence[1~Table~#2,s,#^2]~FreeQ~#)&
```

input format

> [A,N,X,Y]

Answer (score 0):

## PHP>=7.1, 103 Bytes

```php
for([,$n,$d,$s,$e]=$argv,$f=[$s,$e];$x<$n;)$x=$f[]=array_sum(array_slice($f,-$d));echo+in_array($n,$f);
```

[Testcases](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dff03f5bcca97ba038cdc02b31a99cd64a345a32)