# Approximation of e

Tags: code-golf, math, number, approximation

We all know that the [Euler's number](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)), denoted by \$e\$, to the power of some variable \$x\$, can be approximated by using the [Maclaurin Series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html) expansion:

$$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^k}{k!}}=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\dots$$

By letting \$x\$ equal \$1\$, we obtain

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k!}{=\frac{1}{0!}+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}+\dots\\=1+1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{24}+\dots}}$$

### Challenge

Write a program in any language which approximates Euler's number by taking in an input \$n\$ and calculates the series to the \$n\$th term. Note that the first term has denominator \$0!\$, not \$1!\$, i.e. \$n=1\$ corresponds to \$\frac{1}{0!}\$.

### Scoring

Program with least amount of bytes wins.

Comment: Given large enough `N` the results will be the same if using a finite precision floating point number. Is that behaviour acceptable or does the result have to progressively get more accurate as `N` approaches infinity?

Comment: Some test cases would be neat.

Comment: (This kind of issue is preferably resolved in the [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) – if you post your challenges there first, golfers will give useful feedback.)

Comment: Is x^n the nth term or the (n+1)th?

Comment: Hopefully this edit makes any unclear details clearer

Comment: Thanks for editing to improve your question, however I do not think you answered my question or mh210's. Also, while not necessary, test cases are extremely helpful.

Comment: I don't think "Nth term" is unclear at all - the first term is the first term. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Perhaps you have never taken any calculus course before... 1/0! is the first term, 1/1! is the second term, and so on.

Comment: According to the summation notation that you've used, 1/0! actually seems to be the 0th term, not the first. I imagine this point is also what bothered msh210. I would personally recommend adding "`N` may be zero or one indexed" to your post.

Comment: No, it is not the zero-th term; simply because its a series. There is no zero-th term of a non-zero polynomial such as this

Comment: I personally despise it, but there are people who refer to the term at index 0 as zeroth term. Independently of our thoughts on that matter, the question should be as clear as possible. Also, a few test cases to verify that the solutions are working correctly, would be very helpful.

Comment: FWIW, it's quite easy to use this formula to calculate _e_ to large numbers of digits without requiring bignum support. Eric Jensen first did this back in the mid 60s. [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1295561/207316) is a Python 2 version I did a while ago.

Comment: Is there a way of calculating `e` which converges more quickly?

Comment: @Lembik there is another way, but it converges a bit slower: take the limit of `(1+(1/n))^n` as n approaches infinity and you'll obtain `e`. This calculation stems from compound interest, as it is the amount of money you will obtain after a year when the compoundings are calculated more and more often.

Comment: @Lembik There are several other approaches, I believe most continued fraction based approaches are better if designed well, as well as something like various [brothers' formulae](http://www.brotherstechnology.com/math/e-formulas.html).

Comment: I improved formatting, feel free to [rollback](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/8829) if you don't like it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
R’!İS
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=UuKAmSHEsFM&input=&args=MjA)

#### How it works

```
R’!İS  Main link. Argument: n

R      Yield the range [1, ..., n].
 ’     Map decrement over the list.
  !    Map factorial over the list.
   İ   Map inverse over the list.
    S  Compute the sum.
```

Comment: ["Having a built-in for **\[1, n\]** makes more sense than having one for **[0, n)** imho."](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29414311#29414311)

Comment: …and a month and a bit later, Jelly has `Ḷ`, which makes a **[0, n)** range. ^v^;

Answer (score 15):

## [Wistful-C](https://github.com/Nazek42/wistful-c) - 336 bytes

My first real wistful- program! There is actually a little golfing I did, with using `someday` instead of `wait for` because the first had a shorter length.

```
if only <stdio.h> were included...
if only int f were 1...
if only int N were 0...
wish for "%d",&N upon a star
if only int i were 0...
if only double e were 0...
someday i will be N...
        if only e were e+1./f...
        if only i were i+1...
        if only f were f*i...
*sigh*
wish "%f\n",e upon a star
if wishes were horses...
```

Comment: I was told that you don't need to include `<stdio.h>`

Comment: Does `someday i were N...` work instead of `someday i will be N...`?

Answer (score 11):

### Pyth, <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
smc1.!
```

[Try it here.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=smc1.%21&input=100&debug=0)

```
 m      map over range 0..input:
    .!  factorial
  c1    1 / ^
s       sum
```

Thanks to [FryAmTheEggman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31625/fryamtheeggman) for a byte!

Answer (score 10):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), <s>28</s> <s>27</s> 21 bytes

```julia
n->sum(1./gamma(1:n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@59m@z9P1664NFfDUE8/PTE3N1HD0CpPU/N/Wn6RQqaCrYKhlaEBlwIQFBRl5pXk5GmkaWRqanKl5qX8BwA)

This is an anonymous function that accepts an integer and returns a float. To call it, assign it to a variable.

The approach is quite straightforward. We `sum` 1 divided by the gamma function evaluated at each of 1 through *n*. This takes advantage of the property *n*! = Γ(*n*+1).

Saved 1 byte thanks to Dennis and 6 thanks to Glen O!

Comment: Almost exactly the same in MATLAB: `@(n)sum(1./factorial(0:n))`

Answer (score 10):

## TI-84 BASIC, <strike>12</strike> <strike>15</strike> 14

```
Input N
Σ(A!⁻¹,A,0,N
```

TI is a tokenized language ([bytes are counted via tokens](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1541/how-to-score-ti-basic), not individual characters).

Comment: The cited meta post has 11 upvotes and 10 downvotes. That's not a consensus. `Ans` is not a valid input format, so only the 15-byte version is valid.

Comment: fair enough; editing...

Comment: `Ans` has always been the default input format here at PPCG (look through my old TI answers), and more people agree than disagree to that, so don't get bullied into changing your answer.

Comment: There's a simple way to resolve the dispute: Count the number of input *bits* instead of bytes. Now it's an apples-to-apples comparison of the amount of information.

Comment: @MickLH that's not the dispute here. Besides, these are 8-bit bytes.

Comment: @Timtech While I agree with you, community consensus is defined as Mego says.

Answer (score 6):

### Python, 36 bytes

**Python 2:**

```python
f=lambda n,i=1:n/i and 1.+f(n,i+1)/i
```

**Python 3:**

```python
f=lambda n,i=1:i<=n and 1+f(n,i+1)/i
```

Comment: Python 3 variant could be shorter with `or` instead of `and`: `f=lambda n,i=1:i>=n or 1+f(n,i+1)/i`.

Answer (score 6):

## dc, 43 bytes

```
[d1-d1<f*]sf[dlfx1r/r1-d1<e+]se1?dk1-d1<e+p
```

This is a fairly direct translation of the series.  I tried to be cleverer, but that resulted in longer code.

### Explanation

```
[d1-d1<f*]sf
```

A simple factorial function, for n>0

```
[dlfx1r/r1-d1<e+]se
```

Execute the factorial for n,...,1; invert and sum

```
1?dk1-
```

Prime the stack with 1; accept input and set an appropriate precision

```
d1<e+
```

If input was 0 or 1, we can just pass it on, else compute the partial sum.

```
p
```

Print the result.

### Test results

The first 100 expansions:

```
0
1
2
2.500
2.6666
2.70832
2.716665
2.7180553
2.71825394
2.718278766
2.7182815251
2.71828180110
2.718281826194
2.7182818282857
2.71828182844671
2.718281828458223
2.7182818284589936
2.71828182845904216
2.718281828459045062
2.7182818284590452257
2.71828182845904523484
2.718281828459045235331
2.7182818284590452353584
2.71828182845904523536012
2.718281828459045235360273
2.7182818284590452353602862
2.71828182845904523536028736
2.718281828459045235360287457
2.7182818284590452353602874700
2.71828182845904523536028747123
2.718281828459045235360287471339
2.7182818284590452353602874713514
2.71828182845904523536028747135253
2.718281828459045235360287471352649
2.7182818284590452353602874713526606
2.71828182845904523536028747135266232
2.718281828459045235360287471352662481
2.7182818284590452353602874713526624964
2.71828182845904523536028747135266249759
2.718281828459045235360287471352662497738
2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977552
2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775705
2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757231
2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572453
2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724691
2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757247074
2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470919
2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709352
2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093683
2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936984
2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369978
2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699940
2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999574
2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995936
2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959554
2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595729
2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995957475
2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574944
2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595749646
2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995957496673
2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574966943
2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595749669652
2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995957496696740
2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574966967601
2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595749669676254
2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995957496696762747
2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574966967627699
2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595749669676277220
2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995957496696762772386
2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574966967627724050
2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595749669676277240739
2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995957496696762772407632
2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574966967627724076601
2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595749669676277240766277
2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995957496696762772407663006
2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574966967627724076630325
2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595749669676277240766303508
2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995957496696762772407663035328
2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574966967627724076630353518
2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595749669676277240766303535449
2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995957496696762772407663035354729
2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574966967627724076630353547565
2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595749669676277240766303535475915
2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995957496696762772407663035354759429
2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574966967627724076630353547594542
2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595749669676277240766303535475945681
2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995957496696762772407663035354759457111
2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574966967627724076630353547594571352
2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595749669676277240766303535475945713792
2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995957496696762772407663035354759457138185
2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574966967627724076630353547594571382143
2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595749669676277240766303535475945713821752
2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995957496696762772407663035354759457138217826
2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574966967627724076630353547594571382178492
2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595749669676277240766303535475945713821785218
2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995957496696762772407663035354759457138217852481
2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574966967627724076630353547594571382178525131
2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595749669676277240766303535475945713821785251635
2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995957496696762772407663035354759457138217852516607
2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574966967627724076630353547594571382178525166394
```

Using 1000 terms:

```
2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595749669676277240\
766303535475945713821785251664274274663919320030599218174135966290435\
729003342952605956307381323286279434907632338298807531952510190115738\
341879307021540891499348841675092447614606680822648001684774118537423\
454424371075390777449920695517027618386062613313845830007520449338265\
602976067371132007093287091274437470472306969772093101416928368190255\
151086574637721112523897844250569536967707854499699679468644549059879\
316368892300987931277361782154249992295763514822082698951936680331825\
288693984964651058209392398294887933203625094431173012381970684161403\
970198376793206832823764648042953118023287825098194558153017567173613\
320698112509961818815930416903515988885193458072738667385894228792284\
998920868058257492796104841984443634632449684875602336248270419786232\
090021609902353043699418491463140934317381436405462531520961836908887\
070167683964243781405927145635490613031072085103837505101157477041718\
986106873969655212671546889570350116
```

Answer (score 5):

## J, 10 bytes

```
[:+/%@!@i.
```

Straight-forward approach.

### Explanation

```
[:+/%@!@i.    Input: n
        i.    Creates the range [0, 1, ..., n-1]
      !@      Maps factorial to each
    %@        Map 1/x to each
[:+/          Take the sum of the values and return it
```

Comment: Nice.  Trivial 1 byte improvement: `1#.%@!@i.`

Answer (score 4):

## MATL, <s>11</s> 7 bytes

```
:Ygl_^s
```

*4 bytes saved thanks to @Luis's recommendation to use `gamma` (`Yg`)*

[**Try it Online**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OllnbF9ecw&input=MTAw)

**Explanation**

```
        % Implicitly grab input (N)
:       % Create an array from 1...N
Yg      % Compute factorial(x-1) for each element (x) in the array
l_^     % Take the inverse
s       % Sum all elements
        % Implicitly display the result
```

Comment: You can remove `]`

Comment: Also, `1i:Yg/s` for 7 bytes

Comment: @LuisMendo oh yea I was hoping there was a better way to get a factorial but I had forgotten about gamma. Will update shortly

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>44 42</s> 40

```
n=>{for(k=s=m=1;m<n;s+=k/=m++);return s}
```

An unnamed function now.

Thanks for saving 2 bytes @AlexA and thanks to @LeakyNun for another 2 bytes!

Comment: `n=>{for(k=s=m=1;m<n;s+=k/=m++);return s}`

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 11

```
r~,:m!Wf#:+
```

or

```
r~{m!W#}%:+
```

Try it online: [first version](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=r%7E%2C%3Am!Wf%23%3A%2B&input=7) and [second version](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=r%7E%7Bm!W%23%7D%25%3A%2B&input=7)

**Explanation:**

`r~` = read and evaluate
`m!` = factorial
`W#` = raise to the -1 power (`W` = -1)
`:+` = sum of array
First version constructs the [0…N-1] array and applies factorial and inverse to all its elements; 2nd version does factorial and inverse for each number then puts them in an array.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes

```
q_t1Zh
```

This computes the sum using the [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) <sub>1</sub>*F*<sub>1</sub>(*a*;*b*;*z*):

[image]

Works on Octave and on the online compiler, but not on Matlab, due to [a difference](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1822112/91216) in how the hypergeometric function is defined (which will be corrected).

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=cV90MVpo&input=NQ)

#### Explanation

```
q_    % Take N implicitly. Compute -N+1
t     % Duplicate
1     % Push 1
Zh    % Hypergeometric function 1F1(-N+1;-N+1;1). Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 4):

## C, 249 bytes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define z double
z f(z x){z r=1;z n=1;while(x>0){r*=n;n++;x--;}return r;}int main(int argc, char **argv){z e=0;z p=0;z d=0;p=strtod(argv[1],NULL);while(p>0){e+=1.0d/f(d);printf("%.10f\n",e);p--;d++;}return 0;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
/* approximate e */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double fact(double x){
    double result = 1;
    double num = 1;

    while (x > 0){
        result *= num;
        num++;
        x--;
    }
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    double e = 0;
    double precision = 0;
    double denom = 0;

    precision = strtod(argv[1], NULL);
    while (precision > 0){
        e += 1.0d / fact(denom);
        printf("%.10f\n", e);
        precision--;
        denom++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Takes a number as an argument to determine number of iterations.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG! Great first post!

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! I think the program is meant to print only the last approximation. At least with GCC, you don't need the `int` before `main` and the `return 0`. Also, if you replace `NULL` with `0`, you don't need the includes. `argc` and `argv` can be shortened to single-letter variables. If you enjoy golfing in C, you might find [Tips for golfing in C](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2203) helpful.

Comment: IMHO, even if the compiler throws some warnings but returns the correct result nevertheless, you can throw away many parts of your code to the point that nothing could be reduced without an error.

Comment: And you don't need `#include <stdio.h>`

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 bytes

```apl
⍳⊥⊢÷!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/x/1bn7UtfRR16LD2xX/pwGFHvX2QWS7mg@tN37UNhHICw5yBpIhHp7B/9MOrVAwVDBSMFYwUTBVMAMA)

Using the mixed base trick found in [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194817/78410) of [another challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/194801/78410). Uses `⎕IO←0`.

#### How it works

```apl
⍳⊥⊢÷!  Right argument: n, the number of terms
  ⊢÷!  v: 1÷(n-1)!
⍳      B: The array of 0 .. n-1
 ⊥     Expand v to length-n array V,
       then mixed base conversion of V in base B

Base | Digit | Value
--------------------
0    | v     | v×(1×2×..×(n-1)) = 1÷0!
1    | v     | v×(2×3×..×(n-1)) = 1÷1!
2    | v     | v×(3×..×(n-1))   = 1÷2!
..   | ..    | ..
n-2  | v     | v×(n-1)          = 1÷(n-2)!
n-1  | v     | v                = 1÷(n-1)!
```

Comment: 10k rep! Now to see if I can pull this off in Turing Machine....

Comment: Nice answer but I'm having trouble seeing how `1÷(n-1)!` is a digit?  Could you translate it into J to clarify?

Answer (score 3):

### Pyke, 10 bytes

```
FSBQi^R/)s
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=FSBQi%5ER%2F%29s&input=2%0A10)

Or 8 bytes if power=1

```
FSB1R/)s
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=FSB1R%2F%29s&input=10)

Comment: the first code was off by more than 3 when I ran it: 5.436532738095238

Comment: @tox123 fixed now

Comment: are you testing these? I got: 7.3887125220458545 for the first, the second works much better.

Comment: That one is an e^x one you know not just e

Comment: that's not the challenge.

Comment: It was when I wrote it - the challenge changed

Answer (score 3):

## k (13 bytes)

Subject to overflows for `N>20`

```
{+/%*\1,1+!x}
```

Answer (score 3):

### 05AB1E, 6 bytes

```
$L<!/O
```

**Explained**

```
$           # push 1 and input: N = 5
 L<         # range [0..N-1]: [0,1,2,3,4]
   !        # factorial over range [1,1,2,6,24]
    /       # divide 1/range: [1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.16666666666666666, 0.041666666666666664]
     O      # sum: 2.708333333333333
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=JEw8IS9P&input=NQ)

Comment: 5 bytes with [`L<!zO`](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fx0axyv//f1MA).

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 37 bytes

```
((scanl(+)0$(1/)<$>scanl(*)1[1..])!!)
```

Not the shortest, but arguably the prettiest.

---

Also courtesy of [Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56433/laikoni), here is a solution that is **2 bytes** shorter:

```
sum.(`take`((1/)<$>scanl(*)1[1..]))
```

---

```
λ> let f = ((scanl (+) 0 $ (1/) <$> scanl (*) 1 [1..]) !!)

λ> map f [1..5]
[1.0,2.0,2.5,2.6666666666666665,2.708333333333333]

λ> f 10
2.7182815255731922

λ> f 100
2.7182818284590455

λ> log (f 10)
0.9999998885745155

λ> log (f 100)
1.0
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG! This challenge is tagged [tag:code-golf], so please try to minimize the length of your code. Also, you need to post the byte count of your code. Otherwise, great post!

Comment: You can use [this UTF-8 byte counter](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter). I put in a suggested edit to add your byte count, which is `50`. To add a header, use: `## Language, <xxx> bytes`.

Comment: Do you need the whitespace?

Comment: You cannot assume the input to be present in a variable, so you need to prepend `f n=` or `\n->` to get a valid function submission. However, we can also save a few bytes: `(\x->1/x)` can be shortened to the section `(1/)`, `[1,2..]` is the same as `[1..]` and `map(...)$` can be `(...)<$>`. Together 36 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hz7a4NFelJDE7VSFPRcNQX9NGxa44OTEvR0NL0zDaUE8v9n9uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCikKagqHBfwA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: Converting to a point-free function saves another byte: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfpmCrEPO/uDRXTyOhJDE7NUFDw1Bf00bFrjg5MS9HQ0vTMNpQTy9WU/N/bmJmHlBxQVFmXomCikKagqHB/3/JaTmJ6cX/dSOcAwIA "Haskell – Try It Online") And even though it's a byte longer, `((scanl(+)0$(1/)<$>scanl(*)1[1..])!!)` looks nice as well.

Comment: @Laikoni I like that one a lot! Removing the outer parentheses, it's 1 byte shorter than what I had. I edited my answer again.

Comment: Unfortunately the outer parenthesis cannot be removed because they are needed in order to haven an actual function instead of a code snippet.

Comment: As you have seen yourself the version without parentheses is only a valid Haskell expression when inserting a value after it, but as [assuming the input to be present in a predefined variable is not allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8731/56433), you have to add the parentheses or again a leading `\n->` to create a function.

Comment: @Laikoni I edited my answer yet once again. I included the parentheses and gave you credit for the improvements. In fact, at this point, I am temped to suggest that I delete my answer and you post my answer under your name, for you did all the non-trivial work.

Comment: Thanks for the credit! However I would not want post this answer myself as I'd likely would not have thought of it without seeing your answer before. Besides, the culture of helping each other to improve their answers is one of the aspects I enjoy most on this site.

Answer (score 3):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 6 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```
+/÷!⍳⎕
```

`+/` sum of
`÷` the reciprocals of
`!` the factorials of
`⍳` the numbers from 0 to
`⎕` numerical input

Assumes `⎕IO←0`, which is default on many systems.

[TryAPL](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2395IO%u21900%20%u22C4%20%u2395PP%u219017%20%u22C4%20+/%F7%21%u237318&run)!

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 28 bytes

```
f=(n,i=1)=>n&&1+f(n-1,i+1)/i
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```
{1+sum [\/] 1..^$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/2lC7uDRXITpGP1bBUE8vTiW@9n9xYqWCkkq8gq2dQnWaAlBESSEtvwgkbWjwHwA)

*-2 bytes thanks to Jo King*

`[\/]` performs a "triangular reduction" (or "scan") using the division operator over the sequence `1, 2, ..., $_-1` (where `$_` is the argument to the function).  So for example `[\/] 1..4` is the sequence `1`, `1/2`, `1/2/3`, `1/2/3/4`, which are the terms required for the `n = 5` case.

Answer (score 3):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 25 bytes

```
[range(.)+1|1/tgamma]|add
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z@6KDEvPVVDT1PbsMZQvyQ9MTc3MbYmMSXl/38zAA)

jq currently only has IEEE754 double-precision (64-bit) floating point number support, luckily it works in its favour here.

Answer (score 2):

### Actually, 6 bytes

```
r♂!♂ìΣ
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=cuKZgiHimYLDrM6j&input=Nw)

Explanation:

```
r♂!♂ìΣ
r       range(N) ([0, N-1])
 ♂!     factorial of each element
   ♂ì   reciprocal of each element
     Σ  sum
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 18 bytes

```
:1-:0r:ef:$!a:/a+.
```

#### Explanation

```
:1-                 Subtract 1 from Input
   :0r              Create the list [0, Input - 1]
      :ef           Find all integers between 0 and Input - 1
         :$!a       Apply factorial to each member of that list
             :/a    Apply inverse to each element of that list
                +.  Unify the output with the sum of the list
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java with [Ten Foot Laser Pole](https://github.com/SuperJedi224/Ten-Foot-Laser-Pole), <s>238</s> 236 bytes

```
import sj224.tflp.math.*;interface U{static void main(String[]a){BigRational r=null,s,t;r=s=t=r.ONE;for(int n=new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextInt()-1;n-->0;){t=t.multiply(r);s=s.add(t.pow(-1));r=r.add(r.ONE);}System.out.print(s);}}
```

Has much better overflow resistance than most of the other answers. For 100 terms, the result is

```
31710869445015912176908843526535027555643447320787267779096898248431156738548305814867560678144006224158425966541000436701189187481211772088720561290395499/11665776930493019085212404857033337561339496033047702683574120486902199999153739451117682997019564785781712240103402969781398151364608000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 2):

## Maple, 18

```
add(1/i!,i=0..n-1)
```

Usage:

```
> f:=n->add(1/i!,i=0..n-1);
> f(1);
  1
> f(4);
  8/3
```

Comment: I think the function is n->add(1/i!,i=0..n-1)

Answer (score 2):

## C, 69 bytes

```c
double f(int n){double s=1,f=1;for(int i=0;i++<n;s+=f)f/=i;return s;}
```

[Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/MnPt3U)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 28 bytes

```julia
~k=k<1?1:1/gamma(k+1)+~(k-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/@/Lts228bQ3tDKUD89MTc3USNb21BTu04jW9dQ839BUWZeSU6enoZenYaBlZGBpuZ/AA)

### Explanation

```julia
~k=                    #Define ~ to be
    k<1                #If k is less than 1
        ?1             #to be one
        :1/gamma(k+1)  #else add the reciprocal factorial to 
            +~(k-1)    #the function applied to the predecessor value
```

`gamma(k+1)` is equal to `factorial(k)` for positive integer inputs, and generalizes it for all values other than the nonnegative integers. It saves one byte, so why not use it?

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>51</s> 43 bytes

```powershell
param($a)++$p..$a-ge1|%{$s+=$p/=$_}
$s+!!$a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f@/ILEoMVdDJVFTW1ulQE9PJVE3PdWwRrVapVjbVqVA31YlvpYLyFZUVEn8//@/AQA)

-6 bytes thanks to *mazzy*!
-2 bytes thanks to *Zaelin Goodman*!

Comment: [Try it online?](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f9fpcDWkMtQT09JJbEovVhJNz3VsEa1WqVY21alQN9WJb6WC8g2/P//v6EBAA "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")

Comment: Cool approach @mazzy! It doesn't work for `n=0`, though, I added a special case for it

Comment: [43 bytes?](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f@/ILEoMVdDJVFTW1ulQE9PJVE3PdWwRrVapVjbVqVA31YlvpYLyFZUVEn8//@/AQA "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
LwỊ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run?header=&code=Lw%E1%BB%8A&footer=&input=20&flags=S)

##### Explanation

```python
LwỊ  # Implicit input
L    # Lowered range
 w   # Factorial
  Ị  # Reciprocal
     # Sum
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB / Octave, 22 bytes

```
@(x)sum(1./gamma(1:x))
```

Creates an anonymous function named `ans` that can be called using `ans(N)`.

This solution computes [`gamma(x)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gamma.html) for each element in the array [1 ... N] which is equal to `factorial(x-1)`. We then take the inverse of each element and sum all elements.

[**Online Demo**](http://ideone.com/Vacnn2)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 37 bytes

Not a winner, but nice and straightforward:

```
$e=$p=1;$e+=1/($p*=$_)for 1..<>;say$e
```

Outputs for inputs from 0 to 10:

```
1
2
2.5
2.66666666666667
2.70833333333333
2.71666666666667
2.71805555555556
2.71825396825397
2.71827876984127
2.71828152557319
2.71828180114638
```

Answer (score 1):

### R, 17 bytes

```
sum(1/gamma(1:n))
```

Quite straightforward, although numerical precision issues are bound to arise at some point in time.

Answer (score 1):

## [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum1%2Fk!,0..n), 12 bytes

```
sum1/k!,0..n
```

Answer (score 1):

### F#, 87 bytes

```
let rec f x=if x<2 then 1 else f(x-1)*x
let e N=Seq.sumBy(fun x->1./float(f x)){0..N-1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU5PC4IwFL/7KX4EgQu2nGf1EHSVoGN1EHmrgc6aMxTxs69p7/B4/P4@1fO6s@R9Qw6WaiiMuQ4rS@FeZCBBTU9Q8cglO4zRqiOU@ZU@oh/a0xSrwWDkhRRH1XSVi4OZsTkRouRy8bfsbJydLp02rnhs9rbSBpV9fpFHCLNijmzbI8cshUiTZcPXCh0IbBUOvMDbhhhlsCuDdq/v6y/hULtAxwTH2D9p8yf@Bw)

A direct implementation of the Maclaurin expansion. Unfortunately over 35 terms the denominator is too small, so the sum becomes infinity.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 44 bytes

```
n=>{for(a=d=i=1;i<=n;a+=1/d)d/=i++;return a}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>43</s> 42 bytes

-1 byte by calculating using `Rational` instead of `Float`.

```ruby
->n{(0..n).sum{|i|1/(1..i).reduce(1r,:*)}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcpBCoMwEAXQq3yEQFJ02ghuhPYiIqXVBF04lsQsSpKzR0o3b/VceH@LvZfmwVHeiFiRD1tMa9JXqYlWRc7MYTJSu7q/qJzLr@lOkXlNC2LihE84PCrRzj1E03YewlcQGLiGHXj8S8f@tCNyOQE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
òo⌠├p
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=956ff4c370&i=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A10%0A100&a=1&m=2)

Produces output as a fraction.

Answer (score 1):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 7 bytes

```
;1/f_-$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/39pQPy1eV@X/fyMDAA)

## Explanation

```
;           Series - output sum of first n terms in sequence
            Each term is 
 1/                      1 / 
   f   )                     factorial (           )
    _-                                         - 1
      $                                  index
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 26 bytes

```
Sum[1/n!,{n,0,Input[]}]//N
```

Pretty straight forward: takes the sum of the inverse of n factorial, with n starting from 0 and all the way to the desired number. 
The `//N` is used to give an approximate value of the fraction yielded by the sum.
The code can be checked online , for free, via the wolfram programming labs:

[Wolfram Labs](https://www.wolfram.com/programming-lab/)

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice first answer! I've edited your post ever so slightly to improve clarity and to format it in the standard manner for answers on the site (`# <language name>` rather than `** <language> **`)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Thank you very much! I appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

## [k4](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
{+/%*/'1_',\!x}
```

---

```
{             } / lambda
            !x  / enumerate x; (!4 -> 0 1 2 3)
          ,\    / join scan; joins successive elements and returns intermediate results (,0;0 1;0 1 2;0 1 2 3)
       1_'      / 1 drop each; drops leading 0s (();,1;1 2;1 2 3)
    */'         / multiply over each; 1 1 2 6
   %            / reciprocal; 1 1 0.5 0.1666667
 +/             / sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wren](https://wren.io), 81 bytes

```
Fn.new{|N|
var e=0
for(i in 1..N)e=e+1/(1..i).reduce{|a,b|a*b}
return e+1
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY3BCsIwEAXv@Yo9JiqrFTzm6rEXvyCNrxCoK6yNQZp@e2xvwzAwRSHtG5TGLJE8tbuwoCy1r2bX8BczvtUmSkIdc@/gcezOduPkWPHMEUsNp6GGw7AaxZxVaEvM2h6/z4wXF00z7D7gGKbJXm/OtT8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg) `-rr`, <s>18</s> 15 bytes

```
11(¿|:¡1$/"+"1+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///f0FDj0P4aq0MLDVX0lbSVDLWBQv91i4oA)

This took a whole bunch of fiddling to figure out. It works!!

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
L<!zO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fx0axyv//f0MDAwA)

```
L<!zO  # full program
    O  # sum of...
   z   # 1 divided by...
  !    # factorial of...
       # (implicit) each element in...
L      # [1, 2, 3, ...,
       # ..., implicit input...
L      # ]...
       # (implicit) with each element...
 <     # decremented
       # implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
ṁo\Πŀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9odXNr/2kqITnEsOKBsOKCgf/huYFvXM6gxYD///8yMA)

Calculates the sum of the series as a rational number: TIO header converts this to 9 decimal digits (with an implicit point after the first digit).

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), `s`, 3 bytes

```
ʁ¡Ė
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=%CA%81%C2%A1%C4%96&inputs=20&header=&footer=)

Explanation:

```
     # Implicit input
ʁ    # Range [0, N)
 ¡   # Map factorial over all elements
  Ė  # Map inverse over all elements
     # 's' flag: cumulative sum top of stack and output
```

Comment: you have the 's' flag in the title but say the 'd' flag is a cumulative sum, which one are you using?

Comment: @ZippyMagician Whoops, my bad. I had tried `d` first, but `s` was needed. I forgot and put the wrong flag in the explanation. Fixed.

Comment: Dammit, I was just about to post this!

Answer (score 1):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn) `-Rmx`, 3 bytes

```
1/f
```

This can hypothetically be infinitely precise with a large input and the use of the `-p`, `-o`, and `--stack` arguments, as Arn makes use of arbitrarily-precise floating point numbers. Compression doesn't save any bytes here.

## Explained

`-R` transforms input from `N` to the range `[0, N)`.
`-m` maps the program over the input

```
1/      Reciprocal of
   f   The factorial function in the global scope (takes `_`)
```

`-x` then sums the result

### Arn (less boring), 10 bytes uncompressed

```
+{1/f}\0->
```

Same concept but without the flags. This is probably **7-8 bytes compressed**, but I'm not at my computer right now and so can't check.

Comment: Surely this is compressible somehow. 5 bytes feels way too long.

Comment: 1.1 makes it 4 bytes, so it’s possible that can be compressed to 3. It’s really hit and miss when it comes to the text compression.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 33 bytes

Returns a rational number. If the we can use 0-indexing, `...` can be shortened to `..`.

```ruby
->n{[k=1,*1...n].sum{|j|1r/k*=j}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcrBCoQgGEXhV7kEQkX@gw0t9UXExUQIFkVoLkJ9dsfVWXzHx/WtVlaurqQPKaZRENFlKMQz5T0L/zlGuZdS@wZiGej83UjZZdzxCejYvIErMD5/A3rWFjt0YNBugpdWO9NqSv0D)

Comment: I believe you can change `1r/k*=j` into `k/=j`, and set `k=1r` at the start.

Answer (score 1):

## [asm2bf](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Asm2bf), 133 bytes

Requires a 16-bit interpreter, at least 64 tape cells, integer i/o. This all is faciliated using `bfi -d` bundled with asm2bf. Fairly slow, overflows at n=6. Takes `n` in r4. Outputs the result due to [a meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19024/61379).

```
?A=popr1/outr1
@z incr3
psh1
dup
@a movr2,r3
movr1,1
@b cltr2,2
cjn%c
mulr1,r2
decr2
jmp%b
@c pshr1
psh1
fad
incr3
cltr3,r4
cjn%a
A
A
```

Example usage:

```
mov r4, 5
jmp %z
```

Deobfuscated:

```
inc r3
push 1
push 1
@mloop
    mov r2, r3
    mov r1, 1
@loop
    clt r2, 2
    cjnz %done
    mul r1, r2
    dec r2
    jmp %loop
@done
    push r1
    push 1
    fadd
    inc r3
    clt r3, r4
    cjnz %mloop
pop r1
out r1
pop r1
out r1
```

Bonus: optimized brainfuck code:

```
>>>>>>+++++<+>>>>>>>>>>>>+[<<<<+>>>>>>>[>>]>+<<<[<<]<-]<<<<[>>>>+<<<<-]>>>>>>>[>
>]+[<<]<[<<<<+>>>>>>>[>>]>+<<<[<<]<-]<<<<[>>>>+<<<<-]>>>>>>>[>>]+[<<]<<<<[-]+[<<
<<<<<<<<[-]>[<+<<+>>>-]<<<[>>>+<<<-]>[-]+>>>>>>>>>>>[-]+[<<<<<<<<<<<[<<+>>-]<<[>
>>[<+<+>>-]<<[>>+<<-]<-]>>>->>>++>>>>>>>[-]+<<<<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<-]>>>[>>>+
<<<-]>>>[<<<<<<+>>>+>>>>[-<]>]<<[>>>>-<<<<<<<<<<->>>>>>-[<<<+>>>-]<<]>>>[<<<<<<<
+>>>>>>>-]<<<<[-]>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>>>>+>>>>>>>[>>]>+<<<[<<]<<<<<<<<<<<<
<<<-]>>>>>>>>>>[<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>-]>>>>>>>[>>]+[<<]<[<<<<+>>>>>>>[>>]>+<<<[<
<]<-]<<<<[>>>>+<<<<-]>>>>>>>[>>]+[<<]>>[>>]<<-<[<<<<->+>>>-]<-<<-<[>[<+>>>>+<<<-
]>[<+>-]<[>>>[<<+>+>-]<[>+<-]<<-]<[>+<-]>>>>>>[<<<<<[<+>>+<-]<[>+<-]>>>>>>-]<<[<
<<[<+>>>+<<-]>>[<<+>>-]>-]]<[>>[<+>-]>>>>>[<<<<+>>>>-]<<<]<<[-]+[<<]<<<<<<<<<<<[
-]<<+>>>>>>>>>[-]<<<<<<<<<[>>>>>>+<<<<<<-]>[>>>>+<<<<-]>>>>[<<<<<+>+>>>>>[-<]>]<
<[>>>>+<<<<<<<<<->>>>>-[<<<<+>>>>-]<<]>>>[<<<<<<+>>>>>>-]>>>]>>>[-]>>>[>>]<<->[<
<<[<<]<+>>>[>>]>-]<<<[<<]<.[-]>>>[>>]<<->[<<<[<<]<+>>>[>>]>-]<<<[<<]<.
```

To change the output, tweak the first block of `+`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/)

*note that you can get better results faster by increasing the precision of `MathContext`. This would take up one more byte per power of 10 though. This is why I decided to leave it at `9`
If you need to include the `import java.math.*;` that would add another 19 bytes.*

### Using BigDecimals: 241 bytes

```java
static BigDecimal c(int n){var o=BigDecimal.ONE;var c=o;for(int i=0;i++<n;)o=o.add(c.divide(f(o.valueOf(i)),new MathContext(9)));return o;}static BigDecimal f(BigDecimal n){var o=n.ONE;return n.compareTo(o)<1?o:f(n.subtract(o)).multiply(n);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY9NT8MwDIbv@xU5Ogyi7gihQuLjCDuMG@KQpenmkcRV6hamqb@9ZFUFSPhgy/bzWq8PpjdXh@pjxNBQYnHIvQqG9@pCLxZNt/VohfWmbcWzwShOC5FjSvOyZcO59ISVCBmBDSeMu7d3YdKulbPiHJtjyy4o6lg1GWEfwcKqKAop9QQN43zsHnePzmIwXljIpIjy1JskqPzdqPXLkz4PbUm6pjRxWBYal8vbqCWVpExVgVUV9lg5qIFUb3zn1jWglJfRfeafeP9Akd0Xw7XMPpLjLkVBevhvpYY/zY@jOBmZdVFZCo1J7pWA5O3qjm5qiKrttpyM5TyTKnSesfFHiFIP4zB@Aw)

### Using primitive Number types: 119 bytes

```java
static double c(int n){double v=0;for(int i=0;i<n;)v+=1/f(i++);return v;}static double f(int n){return n<2?1:f(n-1)*n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYy7DoIwFIZ3nuKMrQSkjhbiEzgxGofKLUU4JW1pYgjPXhtSB//lXP4v3yicyMb27Zf1NckGmkkYA3chEbYkSSAkNsYKG4ZTsoU59KS2WuLweILQg6EBh5j6Y2w352q1@RIQOyFpCCuKglJ@QLuPslYFdwcNCRQg3eLtqoL3Sh9fGXZZIqcurdi5JzJNKdedXTWC4/u/qP@JIoDl5cauPcGM0RPy3e/@Cw)

Explanation:

```java
    static double c(int n){
        double v=0;               // value for e
        for(int i=0;i<n;)         // for n-iterations
            v+=1/f(i++);          // add the inverse
                                  // of the factorial
        return v;                 // return value
    }

    static double f(int n){
        return n<2?1:f(n-1)*n;    // recursively calculates the factorial
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 4 bytes

```
rFŗ∑
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FsuL3I5Of9QxcUlxUnIxVGzBFkMuIy5jLhMuUy4zLnMuCy5LLkMDiBwA)

```
rFŗ∑
r       Range
 F      Factorial
  ŗ     Reciprocal
   ∑    Sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## x86-64 machine code, 23 bytes

Expects \$n\$ in `rcx` and leaves the result of the approximation in `st0`. The FPU stack is assumed to be empty upon subroutine entry, and only has one value—the result—in it on exit.

Clobbers `rcx`, the FPU stack and flags, and `FLAGS`.

```
d9 e8 d9 e8 d9 e8 eb 0a d9 c1 de c3 d9 e8 de c1 dc f9 e2 f4 da e9 c3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVXRjuo2EH33V4woK3ZVQoBu0Yor@tgPaB/v3iLHdsAXx/bGzm5Wbb99O2MnQC9VVak8ELBnzpw5cxxXPBw/lDg6mLDPlY4BNo9fGPsE3PvW9brhUTsLrga1he@e1pvlI24eY/RhW5bCSXVwpl6EyMVJ9eLI7UEthGvKl04FSg1lSir/hle4ulBUxfLQgOJ@Qc/C0S8HRa1MvaE6RsKwRFtQGAGFfLe80aIw2p5UC6XR1eaxNJIWur7onzbF5nER3GLNmOqjai34VttYz6GuTReOjAUlUleLiAEM8HMwruIG9thHGxnLz23a@gSpOahb3qi04hEE2sqnP6GroA1@Dst@tcTg1Qaq96gCaBui4pKk@9qFCE9Qu3bA4kYfbKNsLt64V4KbEw4bagpuDNSdFVjXNbCC6GC9BG5l7iaF9QiopJ7TF2PGOb@v1EHbTFxjMm2MJVTIkYhOTLIoYDhKBMYZeDu@g3URjqpV7KrRK4hW9HNaIIjOnrRVIUClBO@CQiTsssEhRAXC2Vdsj0TOnkgQ56bGLl0XfReRKeqyHNawjqJu@6ZZwqvmN/LXIXp4eXOthM8o2xfMka6rjEIczEtrI@OXBDP/Jjw/hxojl7q5mgaJSgsX2lmuMZi0zhI5f1ZIND5nrnMvX62Cy1DS0liLfAgEG2KreBNux3nRazDtP3sxsSX7jX5MhKrBR2nsHGe2IWuG97BXvb71Du7R@p6OM@wgs8doqs@YrOB5IpXRjUarPE/YB4V7PEMBLM0OXcHGWQaSlYaJFsYzVak20H4ybu27zJ@RB7JJayNXSU88KaFrcvYa7tFAGGojrBbLh5tI5DGErv5LqNSvA61vo8d56Ba9m1CF62wMQ1sglSjFUaHk0bk8VBwy0d9LtxfHE0u97GnM59cFtvH9LqGNbIho/s2l9Pjvh/nZ8UPWyBMzkdm5jUsWuwqEcjcm5ADKxBoZ9cqjUJFdOs@uKGeeaffMfcyRXeOTTjQvUhdlO6iYekqna2Rdd/iS99lyrYofNya5vGQljzznNHELKbC@t@izO/mwhbvF6kdTP0/oBcrpa7lkE/hpuBMY@9cb4v/eD9yG3fT@wN9OUPw8O9Ofwez34fU4uQtIbbr@cwa//Lqb/TadUUU0Tr4zp/fpWViYIhb8AW/IQDzkK2AyBE2G6EtU38vL3qJExI@/AA)

### Explanation

The algorithm is essentially the same as [@Leaky Nun's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48934/leaky-nun) [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86776/92496), just ported to x64 assembly.

```
func:
    fld1 ; load sum to st2 (constant 1.0)
    fld1 ; load term to st1 (constant 1.0)
    fld1 ; load termdiv to st0 (constant 1.0)

    ; first term counts in rcx dec/check too
    jmp func_do_chk

func_loop:
    ; sum += term
    fld st1
    faddp st3, st0
    
    ; termdiv += 1.0
    fld1
    faddp

    ; term /= termdiv
    fdiv st1, st0

    ; loop back up
func_do_chk:
    loop func_loop

    ; dump st0 and st1 to get sum into st0
    fucompp
    ret
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), <s>85</s> 84 bytes

```go
import."math"
func f(n float64)(S float64){for i:=1.;i<=n;i++{S+=1/Gamma(i)}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BzoLE5OzE9FSF3MTMPK7M3IL8ohI9pbTcEqWlpSVpuhY3Q2BiuYklGUpcaaV5yQppGnkKaTn5iSVmJpoawXBmdVp-kUKmla2hnnWmjW2edaa2dnWwtq2hvntibm6iRqZmLVdRaklpUV4t1Gx7sGkgmzU0Faq5YNpBuo0MwNq5Aooy80py8jQydYC2Qi0CmqSpyVXLBTVmwQIIDQA)

Comment: [84 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BzoLE5OzE9FSF3MTMPK7M3IL8ohI9pbTcEqWlpSVpuhY3Q2BiuYklGUpcaaV5yQppGnkKaTn5iSVmJpoawXBmdVp-kUKmla2hnnWmjW2edaa2dnWwtq2hvntibm6iRqZmLVdRaklpUV4t1Gx7sGkgmzU0Faq5YNpBuo0MwNq5Aooy80py8jQydYC2Qi0CmqSpyVXLBTVmwQIIDQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.factorials math.unicode`, 27 bytes

```
[ iota [ n! -1 ^ ] map Σ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcpBCsIwEAXQvaf4Flwq1qUeQNy4EVelhSFOdDBOajI5kffxSrFIlw@eJ2cx1evldD7u4WN6kZnoHU9OygETHxv/T0Ihzy7qTKLOLCou3hiZ34XVccZhsdvWDhKN0EGXWLcY0E99xPeDvjoKAc3KNxiTqPn6Aw)

### Explanation:

It's a quotation (anonymous function) that takes an integer from the data stack as input and leaves a ratio approximation of `e` on the data stack as output.

- `iota` Create a range from 0 to the input where the input itself is excluded.
- `[ ... ] map` Apply a quotation to each element of a sequence, collecting the results into a new sequence of the same length.
- `n!` Take the factorial.
- `-1 ^` Take the reciprocal. Shorter than `1 swap /` and `recip`.
- `Σ` Sum a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), 71 bytes

```swift
print(Set(0...n).reduce(0){$0+1/Float(Set(1...max(1,$1)).reduce(1,*))})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@Z@TWqKQp2CrYGjwv6AoM69EIzi1RMNAT08vT1OvKDWlNDlVw0CzWsVA21DfLSc/ESJvCJTPTazQMNRRMdSEqzPU0dLUrNX8/x8A)