# Play the sound of Pi

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, pi, audio

Yup, you read the title right. play the sound of pi.

More specifically, for every digit of pi in the first 1000, map it to a musical note and output the resulting melody to a file.

Basically, each digit turns to a note on the C Major scale (basically the normal scale). so 1 turns to Middle C, 2 turns to D4, 3 turns to E4, 9 turns to D5 and so on.

## Rules

- Each note should be exactly 0.5 seconds long.
- The melody should contain the first 1000 digits of pi, including the starting 3.
- 1 to 7 represent Middle C to B4, 8 is C5, 9 is D5 and 0 is E5
- All well supported file formats are allowed, as long as they were created before this challenge.
- There may be no pauses anywhere in the file, including the start and end.
- The instrument played does not matter. It could be a piano, sine wave, anything really, as long as the **correct** sound is easily hearable.
- It must take no input and produce no output except for the file. Reading from other files is disallowed.
- Standard loopholes are forbidden.

Example mathematica code:

```
(*please forgive me for this horrible, horrible mess of code*)
digits = RealDigits[Pi, 10, 1000][[1]] /. {0 -> 10};
weights = {0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12, 14, 16}; 
melody = {};
For[i = 1, i < 1001, i++, melody = {melody , Sound[SoundNote[weights[[digits[[i]]]], 0.5]]}]
final = Sound[Flatten[melody]];
Export["C:\\Mathematica Shenanigans\\pi.wav", final];
```

Example melody showing first 100 digits: http://vocaroo.com/i/s0cfEILwYb8M

For your sanity, A table of pitches for each note and what note does each digit represent:

```
Digit 1: C: 261.63 Hz
Digit 2: D: 293.66 Hz
Digit 3: E: 329.63 Hz
Digit 4: F: 349.23 Hz
Digit 5: G: 392.00 Hz
Digit 6: A: 440.00 Hz
Digit 7: B: 493.88 Hz
Digit 8: C5: 523.25 Hz
Digit 9: D5: 587.33 Hz
Digit 0: E5: 659.25 Hz
```

Comment: _9 turns to D5_ You should clarify that the other notes are in the `4`-th octave. Also, in your table does digit `0` come last (`E5`)?

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes it does. I'll make these too more clear.

Comment: Can we assume 'well supported formats' to mean anything openable by vlc?

Comment: @Pavel Pretty much

Comment: Can I output the note names (e.g. 3.14 --> ECF) if my language does not support sound or writing to sound files?

Comment: @Everyone someone post a TIO link already, I want to hear pi to the millionths place.

Comment: Can I play the notes instead of writing them to a file?

Comment: @BookOwl As long as it's the same as a file, sure!

Comment: @FinW You can write to a midi file, which doesn't need a lot of complicated code and libraries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Mathematica, <s>107</s> 87 bytes

*Thanks to Martin Ender for saving 20 bytes!*

```
"t.au"~Export~Sound[SoundNote[⌊12Mod[#,10,1]/7⌋-1,.5]&/@#&@@RealDigits[Pi,10,1000]]
```

`#&@@RealDigits[Pi,10,1000]` gives the list of the first 1000 digits of π. `SoundNote[⌊12Mod[#,10,1]/7⌋-1` produces the correct pitch number (where 0 is middle C by default) from a digit. Then `SoundNote[...,.5]&/@` turns that pitch name into a sound object of duration 1/2 second, which `Sound` gathers into an actual audio snippet. Finally `"t.au"~Export~` exports to a Unix Audio Format file, mostly because the extension is the shortest supported one, but also because we get to make the filename a [slap in the face to π](https://www.tauday.com/tau-manifesto)!

Previous submission:

```
"t.au"~Export~Sound[StringSplit["E5 C D E F G A B C5 D5"][[#+1]]~SoundNote~.5&/@#&@@RealDigits[Pi,10,1000]]
```

Answer (score 10):

## Python 2, 182 bytes

```python
x=p=6637
while~-p:x=p/2*x/p+2*10**999;p-=2
s="MThd\0\0\0\6\0\1\0\1\342\4MTrk\0\0\13\301\0\220"
for i in`x`:s+="JHGECA@><L\260"[~ord(i)%29]+'{<'
open('p.mid','w').write(s+"\0\377/\0")
```

`` `x` `` will produce `31415926...20198L`. The trailing `L` is used to produce the final channel message byte, via the mapping `~ord(i)%29`.

Outputs a single track Type 1 Midi file, named `p.mid` to the current working directory.

```python
0000: 4d 54 68 64 00 00 00 06  MThd....  # Midi header, 6 bytes to follow
0008: 00 01 00 01              ....      # Type 1, 1 track
000c: e2 04                    â.        # (-)30 ticks per beat, 4 beats per second

000e: 4d 54 72 6b 00 00 0b c1  MTrk...Á  # Track header, 3009 bytes to follow
0016: 00 90 40 7b              ..@{      # Wait  0 ticks, play E4 (3), 97% volume
001a: 3c 3c 7b                 <<{       # Wait 60 ticks, play C4 (1), 97% volume
001d: 3c 41 7b                 <A{       # Wait 60 ticks, play F4 (4), 97% volume
0020: 3c 3c 7b                 <<{       # Wait 60 ticks, play C4 (1), 97% volume
0023: 3c 43 7b                 <C{       # Wait 60 ticks, play G4 (5), 97% volume
...
0bcf: 3c b0 7b 3c              <°{<      # Wait 60 ticks, all notes off
0bd3: 00 ff 2f 00              .ÿ/.      # End of track marker
```

Comment: Quite late, but if you are wondering what pi formula is used, it's a variation on Formula 25 at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html.

Answer (score 6):

## [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/), 530 bytes

*Inspired by [BookOwl's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107609).*

[Online Demonstration](https://phosphorus.github.io/app.html?id=141539239&turbo=false&full-screen=false). Playback will begin immediately, press <kbd>space</kbd> to stop and reset. Click the cat to start again.

**Edit:** golfed down slightly. I found some golfing tips on the [official wiki](https://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Block_Plugin/Syntax#Shortening_Source_Code).

```
when gf clicked
set[c v]to[4e3
repeat(c
add[2e3]to[f v
end
repeat(250
set[b v]to(c
set[h v]to((d)mod(1e4
change[c v]by(-16
repeat(b
set[d v]to(((d)*(b))+((1e4)*(item(b)of[f v
set[g v]to(((2)*(b))-(1
replace item(b)of[f v]with((d)mod(g
set[d v]to(((d)-((d)mod(g)))/(g
change[b v]by(-1
end
change[h v]by(((d)-((d)mod(1e4)))/(1e4
repeat(4
add((h)mod(10))to[a v
set[h v]to(((h)-((h)mod(10)))/(10
end
repeat(4
say(item(last v)of[a v
play note((round((((item(last v)of[a v])-(1))mod(10))*(1.78)))+(60))for(0.5)beats
delete(last v)of[a v
```

**Graphical:**

[image]

Uses the Rabinowitz Wagon spigot to produce 4 digits at a time.

Answer (score 3):

## R, 450 bytes

```
N=261.63*(2^(1/12))^c(16,0,2,4,5,7,9,11,12,14);S=44100;s=unlist(sapply(el(strsplit(as(Rmpfr::Const("pi",1e5),"character"),""))[c(1,3:1001)],function(x)sin(0:(0.5*S-1)*pi*2*N[(x:1)[1]+1]/S)));c=32767*s/max(abs(s));a=file("p.wav","wb");v=writeChar;w=function(x,z)writeBin(as.integer(x),a,z,e="little");v("RIFF",a,4,NULL);w(36+S*10,4);v("WAVEfmt ",a,8,NULL);w(16,4);w(c(1,1),2);w(S*1:2,4);w(c(2,16),2);v("data",a,4,NULL);w(2*length(s),4);w(c,2);close(a)
```

Uses package `Rmpfr` to get the correct precision on pi digits. Outputs a `.wav` file.

Indented, with new lines and comments:

```r
N=261.63*(2^(1/12))^c(16,0,2,4,5,7,9,11,12,14) # Frequency of each notes
S=44100 #Sampling rate
s=unlist(sapply(el(strsplit(
                   as(Rmpfr::Const("pi",1e5),"character"), #get pi correct digits as a character string
                   ""))[c(1,3:1001)], #Grabs first 1000 digits
                function(x)sin(0:(0.5*S-1)*pi*2*N[(x:1)[1]+1]/S))) #Wave function
c=32767*s/max(abs(s)) #Normalize to range [-32767;32767] as per wav 16-bit standard
a=file("p.wav","wb")
v=writeChar
w=function(x,z)writeBin(as.integer(x),a,z,e="little")
v("RIFF",a,4,NULL)     #ChunkID
w(36+S*10,4)           #Chunksize
v("WAVEfmt ",a,8,NULL) #Format, followed by SubChunk1ID
w(16,4)                #SubChunk1Size
w(c(1,1),2)            #AudioFormat & NumChannels
w(S*1:2,4)             #SampleRate & ByteRate
w(c(2,16),2)           #BlockAlign & BitsPerSample
v("data",a,4,NULL)     #SubChunk2ID
w(2*length(s),4)       #Subchunk2Size
w(c,2)                 #Actual data
close(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

### C (gcc) 572 bytes

```
p(float f){i;char b[10000];p=3.14;for(i= 0;i<5000;i++){b[i]=35*sin(f*(2*p*i)/10000);putchar(b[i]);}} f(){i;FILE *f;char p[1001];float n[10];n[0]= 261.63;for(i=1;i<=6;i++){if(i==3)n[i]=349.23;else n[i]=1.12231*n[i-1];}for(i=7;i<=9;i++)n[i]=2*n[i-7];f=popen("pi 1000","r");fgets(p,sizeof(p)-1,f);for(i=0;i<999;i++){switch(p[i]){case'1':p(n[0]);break;case'2':p(n[1]);break;case'3':p(n[2]);break;case'4':p(n[3]);break;case'5':p(n[4]);break;case'6':p(n[5]);break;case'7':p(n[6]);break;case'8':p(n[7]);break;case'9':p(n[8]);break;case'0':p(n[9]);break;default:p(n[0]);break;}}}
```

Ungolfed version:

```
void play(float freq)
{
    char buffer[10000];
    float pi=3.14;
    for(int i = 0; i<5000; i++)
    {
       buffer[i] = 35*sin(freq*(2*pi*i)/10000 );
       putchar(buffer[i]);
    }
}

void f()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char pi[1001];
    float note[10];
    note[0]= 261.63;

    for(int i=1;i<=6;i++)     
    {
       if(i==3)
         note[i]=349.23;
       else
         note[i]=1.12231*note[i-1]; 
    }      

    for(int i=7;i<=9;i++)
      note[i]=2*note[i-7];

   fp=popen("pi 1000","r" );
   fgets(pi, sizeof(pi)-1, fp);  

   for(int i=0;i<1001;i++)
   {
    switch(pi[i])
    {   
        case '1': play(note[0]);break;
        case '2': play(note[1]);break;
        case '3': play(note[2]);break;
        case '4': play(note[3]);break;
        case '5': play(note[4]);break;
        case '6': play(note[5]);break; 
        case '7': play(note[6]);break;
        case '8': play(note[7]);break;
        case '9': play(note[8]);break;
        case '0': play(note[9]);break;
        default : play(note[0]);break;
    }

  }     
}
```

Explanation:

- `play(float freq)` routine takes in the frequency as a parameter of the note (hardcoded) you want to play and stores a sine wave in a buffer.
- In the function `f()`, i stored the frequencies corresponding to notes ranging from C4 to E5  in a `notes` array.
- Store the `pi` value followed by 1000 digits in a buffer.In order to do this, I installed the `pi` package on my machine, and used `popen` to read the output of `pi 1000` and store it in a `char` buffer.
- Using a `for` loop and `switch` I called the `play()` function to produce notes that correspond to every single digit in the `pi` buffer. ,

Usage: `./binary_name.o | aplay` on modern Linux distributions, on older distributions you would redirect it to `/dev/audio`

Comment: Suggest replacing the entire `switch(foo){...}` with something like `play(note[(foo-'1')%10])`. Also, read [tips for golfing in C](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2203/tips-for-golfing-in-c)