# Stay away from zero

Tags: code-golf, number, integer

## Task

Given a non-negative integer `n`, output `1` if `n` is `0`, and output the value of `n` otherwise.

## Input

A non-negative integer.

- If you would like to accept the string as input, the string would match the following regex: `/^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/`, i.e. it must not have any leading zeroes, except when it is `0`.
- If you accept a real integer as input, you may assume that the integer is within the handling capability of the language.

## Output

A positive integer, specified above. Leading zeroes are not allowed. Your output should match the regex `/^[1-9][0-9]*$/`.

## Testcases

```
input output
    0      1
    1      1
    2      2
    3      3
    4      4
    5      5
    6      6
    7      7
```

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.

[Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/48934) apply.

Comment: You should probably put a link to the [TNB CMC](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37110569#37110569), since that's where this challenge came from.

Comment: Does the answer need to be a full function, or can it be the body?

Comment: @CalebKleveter The default rule in PPCG is that the answer is either a function or a full program, but not snippets.

Comment: Can we print the output with a leading zero?

Comment: @MDXF yes, you can.

Comment: @LeakyNun the question text says "leading zeros are not allowed" but your comment contradicts this

Comment: I don't know if that can be written this way but I did it anyway, legal or not: `∃E∃F∃f:E↦F,∀x∃y,x∈E∧y∈F→(x=0→y=S(x))∧(¬x=0→y=x)`.

Answer (score 23):

## C (gcc), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
f(n){n=n?:1;}
```

*Thanks to @betseg for reminding me of the `n?:1` trick in the comments of the other C answer!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@5@mkadZnWebZ29laF37PzOvRCE3MTNPQ5OrmksBCAqKgEJpGkqqKTF5qilKOgppGgaaINJUU9Oaq/Y/AA)

## C, 17 bytes

```
f(n){return!n+n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@5@mkadZXZRaUlqUp5innWdd@z8zr0QhNzEzT0OTq5pLAQgKioBCaRpKqikxeaopSjoKaRoGmiDSVFPTmqv2PwA)

## C, 16 bytes

```
#define f(n)!n+n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@6@ckpqWmZeqkKaRp6mYp533PzOvRCE3MTNPQ5OrmksBCAqKgEJpGkqqKTF5qilKOkClBpog0lRT05qr9j8A)

Comment: https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@6@ckpqWmZeqkKaRp6mYp533PzOvRCE3MTNPQ5OrmksBCAqKgEJpGkqqKUo6CsZaaRqmmprWXLX/AQ hmmm...

Comment: @betseg That's because it's a macro. The compiler sees it as `3*!n+n` which equals `3*0+5`.

Comment: I know, but I think you should be able to apply arithmetic operators to the "return" values directly, that's why it's common practice to put parentheses around macros. I just don't think that the macro is valid.

Comment: @betseg I don't think that's a requirement in code golf. I've never seen a code golf answer with C macros do that.

Comment: I wonder how is this code can even be compiled. Please explain.

Comment: @hucancode See the TIO links. You need to add a `main` from which the function/macro `f` is called. [A solution doesn't need to be a full program by default.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet) The gcc-specific version may or may not compile on another compiler, and it may or may not run correctly when compiled on another compiler.

Comment: @hucancode as for `?:`, omitting middle term is allowed by some compilers. E.g. `-std=gnu89` passed to GCC (which is its default mode) will compile this without errors.

Comment: Does `f(n){n+=!n;}`not work?

Comment: @l4m2 No, it doesn't. At least [on TIO](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zOk/bVjHPuvZ/Zl6JQm5iZp6GJlc1lwIQFBQBhdI0lFRTYvJUU5R0FNI0DDRBpKmmpjVX7X8A).

Answer (score 18):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 bytes

```
ª1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@39oleH//wYA)

#### Explanation

`ª` is a shortcut for JS's `||` operator. Japt has implicit input, so this program calculates `input||1`, and the result is implicitly sent to STDOUT.

`w1` would work as well, taking the maximum of the input and `1`.

Answer (score 18):

### JavaScript (ES6), 7 bytes

```js
n=>n||1
```

Comment: Alternative: `n=>n+!n` (At least I think)

Comment: @SIGSEGV Yes, that would work indeed. (That could also be `n|!n`, although this one is limited to a 31-bit quantity.)

Comment: this can be simplified to n||1.  Only thing that evaluates to false is 0.

Comment: @ansiart If your point is that `n=>n||1` could be simplified to `n||1`, then no. Acceptable answers are either full programs or functions. `n=>do_something_with(n)` is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in ES6 syntax.

Comment: Why not `n|1`...? It makes sure the 1s place is always 1, making it not possible for it to be 0

Comment: @StanStrum We're required to return the original value of `n` if it's not zero. A bitwise OR would modify `n` whenever the least significant bit is not set (e.g. `(4|1) === 5`).

Answer (score 18):

### Haskell, 5 bytes

```
max 1
```

Usage example: `(max 1) 0` -> `1`.

Nothing much to explain.

Answer (score 16):

## Pyth, 2 bytes

```
+!
```

[Try it online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2B!&input=42&debug=0)

Explanation

```
+!
 !Q    1 if (implicit) input is 0, 0 otherwise.
+  Q   Add the (implicit) input.
```

Answer (score 15):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 7 bytes

```
1/s
o@i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@2@oX8yV75D5/78BAA)

#### Explanation

```
1   Push 1. Irrelevant.
/   Reflect to SE. Switch to Ordinal.
i   Read all input as a string.
    Reflect off bottom right corner. Move back NW.
/   Reflect to W. Switch to Cardinal.
1   Push 1.
    IP wraps around to last column.
s   Sort swap: implicitly convert the input to an integer. Then, if the top stack 
    element is less than the one below, the two are swapped. It basically computes
    min and max of two values at the same time, with max on top.
/   Reflect to NW. Switch to Ordinal.
    Immediately reflect off the top boundary. Move SW.
o   Implicitly convert the result to a string and print it.
    Reflect off bottom left corner. Move back NE.
/   Reflect to S. Switch to Cardinal.
@   Terminate the program.
```

Answer (score 14):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 4 bytes

```
é0À
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@394pcHhBsb///8bAQA)

Abuses an *non-preferred but expected behavior*, so I can't really call it a bug. Explanation:

In Vim, commands accept a count. For example, `<C-a>` will increment a number, but `7<C-a>` will increment a number by 7. However, you can't use `0` as a count, because

- `0` is already a command (go the first column), and
- In the context of a text editor, it rarely makes sense to request that a command be run 0 times.

This is fine for a text editor, but usually obnoxious for a golfing language, so V overwrites some commands so that `0` is a valid count. For example, `é`, `ñ`, `Ä`, and some others. However, since `<C-a>` is a builtin vim command, it is not overwritten, so running this with a positive input gives:

```
N       " N times:
 <C-a>  "   Increment
```

But running with 0 as input gives:

```
0       " Go to column one
 <C-a>  " Increment
```

Full explanation:

```
é0          " Insert a 0
  À         " Arg1 or 1 times:
   <C-a>    " Increment
```

Comment: The one time that `0` not being a count is useful.  I didn't even consider it at first because I've avoided it so many times

Answer (score 13):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 2 bytes

```
^*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@59maxWn9f9/moKBgqGCkYIxAA)

`^` [argument] raised to the power of

`*` the sign of the argument (0 if 0 else 1)

Because `1=0^0` in J.

Answer (score 11):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 4 bytes

```
^0
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#U9VwT/gfZ8Bl@P8/kOAy4jLmMuEy5TLjMuey4LLkMgQKGgIA)

If the input starts with a zero, replace that with a 1. (Works because the input is guaranteed to have no leading zeros for non-zero values.)

Answer (score 10):

## R, 13 bytes

```
max(1,scan())
```

reads `n` from stdin. With `pmax`, it can read in a list and return the appropriate value for each element in the list for +1 byte.

[try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/r#@5@bWKFhqFOcnJinoan534DrPwA)

I should note that there is another fine R solution in 13 bytes by [Sven Hohenstein](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118847/67312) which allows for yet *another* 13 byte solution of

```
(n=scan())+!n
```

which makes me wonder if that's the lower limit for R.

Comment: Another 13 bytes solution using `pryr`: `pryr::f(n+!n)`. Can't find anything smaller...

Answer (score 10):

## dc, 7

```
?d0r^+p
```

Relies on the fact that `dc` evaluates 0<sup>0</sup> to 1, but 0<sup>n</sup> to 0 for all other n.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#S8svUihJLS5JTixOVcjMU6g20NMzr7VWSMnnUgCCgqLMvJI0BSXVYgVdOwUlBRWYWrBsanJGPkJIoUYhJVlBN1X9v32KQVGcdsF/da6U/LzU/wA).

Answer (score 10):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), 8 bytes

```
+>,[>]<.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#Tc1LCsIwFEbhcbOKn9KZJs1M0JCNiIM@EgjKveEmhaJ17VUcuYDznWmo8CDWzyBsxgjnYPaDP179zZndKBVZQEiEl7XG2NMbF8ysmiyJakTb0RmtatZ1hhboXL6EQ0fY0HOufU2sqwxUcnoEKf0oQ6K4TPf/64Zfn4uamcL@AQ)

Comment: The paths to the Brainfuck compiler have changed, [here is a fixed TIO demo](https://tio.run/##TY2xDsIgGAbn8hRfmm7KXzYTJbyIcYC2RGLyQwCTRuuzo3HR7Za7c7Zc22QrDDjKx5IjOQ@tQW1n9mdz0dRICB8zGIHxVIpIHV44YY6iSzlw9egHPqIX3brOkBkylU9CY2BsGGOqo8s2sL9Ptx/9/zZ8zVTEHHlpbw)

Answer (score 9):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 6 bytes

```
OI!1L@
```

Somehow managed to fit it on a unit cube... [Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=T0khMUxA&input=MA==&speed=10)

#### Explanation

Before being run, the code is arranged as a cube net:

```
  O
I ! 1 L
  @
```

The IP (instruction pointer) is then placed on the far-left face (`I`), facing to the right. The instructions run from there are:

```
I  Input a number from STDIN and push it to the stack.
!  If the top number is non-zero, skip the next instruction.
1  Push a 1 (only if the input was zero).
L  Turn left. The IP is now on the top face facing the !.
O  Output the top item as a number.
```

The IP then hits `!` again, skipping the `@` on the bottom face. This is not helpful, as we need to hit the `@` to end the program. The IP hits the `L` again and goes through the middle line in reverse (`L1!I`) before ending up on the `L` one more time, which finally turns the IP onto `@`.

Answer (score 7):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 5 bytes

```
ç^0/<C-a>
```

Where `<C-a>` is `0x01`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@394eZyBPuP//wZchlxGXMZcJlymXGZc5lyGBgA)

#### Explanation

```
ç                   " On every line
 ^0/                " that begins with a zero do:
    <C-a>           " Increment the number on that line
```

Comment: [A little competition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118462/31716) :)

Answer (score 7):

## [Oasis](https://github.com/Adriandmen/Oasis), 2 bytes

Uses the following formula: **a(0) = 1**, **a(n) = n**

```
n1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/oasis#@59n@P//fxMA)

Comment: Nice. My approach was `>V`.

Comment: @LeakyNun Oh nice!

Answer (score 7):

### **R**  <strike>20</strike> 16 bytes

```
pryr::f(n+(n<1))
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Thanks @MartinEnder. I am already learn some tricks of the trade.

Answer (score 6):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>22</s>, 10 bytes

```
({{}}[]{})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@69RXV1bGx1bXav5/78BAA)

Explanation:

If the input is non-zero, then `{{}}` will pop everything off the stack and evaluate to the input. If it is zero, nothing will be popped, and it will evaluate to zero. So running `({{}})` gives

Non-zero:

```
n
```

Zero:

```
0
0
```

At this point, we'll add the height of the stack (0 for non-zero, 1 for zero) and pop one more value off the stack. (since the stack is padded with an infinite number of 0's, this will pop either the top 0 or an extra 0)

Comment: Nice job, but not the shortest solution: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118520/31203

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 3 bytes

```apl
1∘⌈
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#@@/4qG2C4aOOGY96Ov7/d1Qw4HJUMARiIyA2BmITIDYFYjMgNgcA)

This takes the ceil of the argument and `1`.

Answer (score 6):

## Jelly, 2 bytes

```
+¬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@699aM3///9NjAA)

Pretty much exactly my Pyth answer, but it's my first Jelly program.

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 3 bytes

```
∅1|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@/@oo9Ww5v9/4/9RAA)

#### Explanation

If we add the implicit `?` (Input) and `.` (Output), we have:

```
?∅          Input is empty (that is, [] or "" or 0 or 0.0)
  1.        Output = 1
    |       Else
     ?.     Input = Output
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), <del>7</del> 6 bytes

```
)?<@.!
```

#### Expanded:

```
 ) ?
< @ .
 ! .
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/hexagony#@69pb@Ogp/j/vyEA)

Saved 1 byte thanks to Martin!

If the number is nonzero print it, otherwise add one to it and print that instead.

Answer (score 5):

## Python, 15 bytes

```
lambda n:n or 1
```

Comment: Why not just `n or 1`, 6 bytes?

Comment: Because that's just a snippet, while we usually answer with complete programs or functions. I'm not sure if this is stated explicitly in some rules somewhere, but at least that's the de facto standard.

Comment: Quoting [trichoplax](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37158069#37158069): `The rules are not terribly clear. I think we have a consensus on meta that REPLs count, but as a separate language, which would allow snippets in many cases, but snippets are not permitted according to this meta post` -> https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422

Comment: Alternative with the same 15-bytes byte-count: [`lambda n:n|1>>n`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKq/G0M4u739afpFCpkJmnkJRYl56qoaBjqGBphWXgkJBUWZeiUKmTppGpuZ/AA)

Comment: One more notable 15 byter is [`lambda n:1-2%~n`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPylDXSLUu739BUWZeiUZ0mkaFpkJafpFChUJmnkJRYl56qoahgWas5n8A), other than that there are some variations of Kevin's function (`n+0**n`, `1>>n^n`, ...)

Answer (score 5):

## [MarioLANG](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MarioLANG), 12 bytes

```
;
=[
:<+
 =:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/mariolang#@2/NZRvNZWWjzaVga/X/vykA)

**How it works**

Mario starts in the top left, initially walking right. He reads an int from input (`;`) and stores it in the current memory cell. Then he falls off the ground (`=`), hitting `[`, which makes him ignore the next command if the current cell is 0.

If the cell is not 0, he'll start walking left (`<`), output the current cell as an int (`:`), and fall to his death (end of program).

If the cell is 0, he ignores the command to turn left, and keeps walking right. He increments the current cell (`+`), outputs it, and falls to his death.

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, <strike>9</strike> 8 bytes

Per Martin Ender:

```
#~Max~1&
```

First idea:

```
#/. 0->1&
```

Pure function with replaces `0` with `1`. The space is necessary or it thinks we are dividing by `.0`.

Answer (score 4):

## TI-BASIC, 7 bytes

```
:Prompt X
:X+not(X
```

Alternatively,

## TI-BASIC, 7 bytes

```
:Prompt X
:max(X,1
```

Answer (score 4):

### Java 8, 10 bytes

```
i->i<1?1:i
```

- Thanks to [@LeakyNun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48934/leaky-nun) for saving -**1** byte

  - Didn't notice it's a **non-negative** integer

Comment: `i==0` can be replaced by `i<1`

Answer (score 4):

## dc, 11 bytes

```
[1]sf?d0=fp
```

`[1]sf` stores a macro in register f which pushes 1 to the top of the stack,
`?` reads input,
`d0=f` runs macro f if input was 0, `p` prints the top of the stack.

Test:

```
$ dc -e "[1]sf?d0=fp" <<< 0
1
$ dc -e "[1]sf?d0=fp" <<< 1
1
$ dc -e "[1]sf?d0=fp" <<< 42
42
```

Answer (score 4):

### Excel, 10 Bytes

```
=A1+(A1=0)
```

This saves 4 Bytes over the obvious 'IF' statement solution, `=IF(A1=0,1,A1)`.

Comment: And 1 byte less than the less obvious `=A1+NOT(A1)`

Answer (score 4):

## Perl 5, 6 + 2 bytes for the -l and -p flags

```
$_||=1
```

Takes input on separate lines from stdin. Runs with the flags `-lp`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 8 bytes

```
!?_:1_;
```

Explanation:

```
 ?       If last element on stack > 0
!        Prevent if check from consuming last element on stack
  _      Pop last element on stack and print
   :     Else
    1    Add int literal 1 to end of stack
     _   Pop last element on stack and print
      ;  Prevent automatic pop of last element on stack
```

Comment: Is this your language?

Comment: Yup, literally got bored at work today and decided to make a language. As you can tell it's very WIP, this is one of the only challenges that it can do beyond simply printing a string

Comment: Congratulations on your new language!

Answer (score 4):

## Arnold C, 303 bytes

```
IT'S SHOWTIME
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE i
YOU SET US UP 1
GET YOUR ASS TO MARS i
DO IT NOW
I WANT TO ASK YOU A BUNCH OF QUESTIONS AND I WANT TO HAVE THEM ANSWERED IMMEDIATELY
BECAUSE I'M GOING TO SAY PLEASE i
TALK TO THE HAND i
BULLSHIT
TALK TO THE HAND 1
YOU HAVE NO RESPECT FOR LOGIC
YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED
```

Trying to explain it:

```
IT'S SHOWTIME //main()
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE i //int i
YOU SET US UP 1 //i = 1
GET YOUR ASS TO MARS i // ? compiler told me to add that
DO IT NOW // ? compiler told me to add that
I WANT TO ASK YOU A BUNCH OF QUESTIONS AND I WANT TO HAVE THEM ANSWERED IMMEDIATELY // something related to reading from stdin
BECAUSE I'M GOING TO SAY PLEASE i // if(i)
TALK TO THE HAND i //print i
BULLSHIT //else
TALK TO THE HAND 1 //print 1
YOU HAVE NO RESPECT FOR LOGIC //endif
YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED //end main()
```

It even beats [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118534/65870)!

Answer (score 4):

### R, 13 bytes

```
n=scan();n+!n
```

Here, `scan` is used to read the input value `n`. The negation of `n` (i.e., `!n`, 0 or 1) is added to `n`.

Answer (score 4):

## GCC command line, 9 bytes

```
-Df(x)x?:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@//9/Zl6JQm5iZp6GJlc1lwIQpOUXKWiARDNtDawVMm0MgaS2dqYmWBIECoqAsmkaSqopVgqqKTF5SjoKmToKaRqZmprWXLX//yWn5SSmF//XdUnTqNCssLcCAA)

`-D` in GCC checks if the following content has an `=`; if not, it add the code

```
#define <followed_content> 1
```

which in this case turns into

```
#define f(x)x?: 1
```

Comment: On meta I gave a common solution but here I give a pointed one

Comment: Can the downvoter leave a comment? I find this very creative.

Answer (score 4):

## Sinclair ZX81/Timex TS1000/1500 BASIC ~19 tokenized BASIC bytes

```
 1 INPUT A
 2 PRINT A+NOT A
```

This is a more efficient solution than the one below; essentially it takes the `NOT` value of `A` (which would be zero in all cases but zero) and adds that to the value of `A`.

Old answer:

#### Sinclair ZX81/Timex TS1000/1500 BASIC, ~31 tokenized BASIC bytes

```
 1 INPUT A
 2 IF NOT A THEN LET A=NOT A
 3 PRINT A
```

This takes a numeric input from the user and will display `1` if zero is entered by making `A` `NOT A`; otherwise it does nothing and displays the numeric value.

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 11 bytes

```
->n{n|1>>n}
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Forte](https://github.com/judofyr/forter), 25 bytes

```
9LET0=1:INPUT2:PRINT2:END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKkn9/9/SxzXEwNbQytMvIDTEyCogyNMPSLn6ufz/bwAA)

#### Explanation

Clearly, the best way to approach this challenge is to define 0 to be 1. Problem solved.

Seriously. That's exactly what this program does.

```
9          Line number (doesn't matter as long as it's not 0 or 2)
 LET 0=1   Redefine 0 to be 1; all future occurrences of 0 will evaluate as 1
 INPUT 2   Redefine 2 to be a number read from input; all future occurrences of 2 will
           evaluate as the input number, though of course if that number was 0 it
           actually evaluates as 1
 PRINT 2   Print that number
 END       End the program
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/), 517 bytes

```
Go to Post Office:w 1 l 1 r 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.Go to The Babelfishery:s 1 l 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:n 1 l 1 l 2 r.Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Pickup a passenger going to Knots Landing.Go to Knots Landing:n 2 r 2 r 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Go to Addition Alley:w 1 r 1 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.Go to The Babelfishery:n 1 r 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:n 1 l 1 r.
```

Formatted for humans:

```
Go to Post Office:w 1 l 1 r 1 l.
Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
Go to The Babelfishery:s 1 l 1 r.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Cyclone:n 1 l 1 l 2 r.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Pickup a passenger going to Knots Landing.
Go to Knots Landing:n 2 r 2 r 1 l.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Go to Addition Alley:w 1 r 1 l 2 l.
Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
Go to The Babelfishery:n 1 r 1 r.
Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.
Go to Post Office:n 1 l 1 r.
```

The key location is Knots Landing which performs the `NOT` operation so `0` returns `1` and all other numbers return `0`. Now, you can go to Addition Alley to add the result from Knots Landing to the original input.

Answer (score 3):

## x86-64 Assembly, <strike>10</strike> 9 bytes

Following the standard [System V AMD64 calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI), this function accepts a 32-bit unsigned integer parameter via the `EDI` register, and returns the result via the `EAX` register:

```
89 F8  |     mov   eax, edi    ; move parameter from EDI to EAX
85 C0  |     test  eax, eax    ; test input and set flags
75 01  |     jnz   Finished    ; if input is non-zero, then jump to end
FF 40  |     inc   eax         ; otherwise, input is 0, so increment it to 1
       |  Finished:
C3     |     ret               ; return, leaving result in EAX
```

---

## x86-32 Assembly, 8 bytes

We could also write this as 32-bit code, since we're only dealing with 32-bit values.

The nice thing about this is that the `INC` instruction becomes only 1 byte in length. (In 32-bit mode, `inc eax` can be encoded simply as `40`. In 64-bit mode, `40` is interpreted as a REX prefix, so the leading `FF` is needed. See [Intel's documentation](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/INC.html) for this instruction.)

The caveat is that *most* 32-bit calling conventions pass parameters on the stack, rather than in registers, and loading a value from the stack (memory) takes many more bytes. If we can be allowed a [`__fastcall`-style calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_fastcall) that passes parameters in registers (supported by virtually all C compilers, so not really cheating, just a bit less standard), then the integer parameter is passed in `ECX` and we get the following code, for a total of 8 bytes:

```
89 C8  |     mov  eax, ecx
85 C0  |     test eax, eax
75 01  |     jnz  Finished
40     |     inc  eax
       |  Finished:
C3     |     ret
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: `xchg eax, edi` is only 1 byte and is fine since you don't need to keep a copy of the value.  Or use a calling convention like GCC's regparm (`-mregparm=3`) that passes the first arg in EAX already.  [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165020)

Comment: Or following an ARM machine-code answer's idea, `mov eax, edi` / `neg edi` (setting CF for any non-zero input) / `sbb eax, -1` to add 1 or 0 (-(CF + -1)).  Unfortunately no shorter unless we can use `sbb al, -1` (2 bytes)

Comment: Thanks, @Peter, for the review. I wrote this answer back before I knew it was legitimate to adopt custom calling conventions in assembly answers. I probably won't update it myself at this point; feel free to do so without stepping on my toes. Or post a separate answer.

Comment: There's already [a quite clever 5-byte x86 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151115/30206) with the function entry point in the middle of a block, using `jecxz` to run an `inc ecx`, taking full advantage of fastcall and of 1-byte `xchg`

Answer (score 3):

## x86 opcode, <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
       41                         INC     ECX
entry: E3 FD                      JECXZ   SHORT $-1
       91                         XCHG    EAX,ECX
       C3                         RETN
```

`ECX` `->` `EAX`

Comment: You'll need to add a length in bytes, so other users can tell how long it is. Generally assembly or byte/op-code languages are measured in the size of the instructions the source represents.

Comment: fixed. forgot.   `    `

Comment: Damn, I just came up with `E3 01 49 41 C3`.

Comment: @2x-1 yeah if returning in ECX it can be 1B shorter

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, 9 bytes

```java
n->n|1>>n
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LU5BDoJADLzzioYTmw1EDl5E@IFcOKqHdQFThELYhcQob18LkrSTdKYzmUbNKmzKl9OtMgYuCunjASDZaqyVriBfz40AHaxIImFm4eUxVlnUkANBCo7CjL5xlpFLPBaH6dGyuP/MPZbQcX5Q2BHpeb2DEv/wuh@3aEzDYwJ4jg@MUopNBCjexlZd1E82GthpWwpQ@qeb9SVFXErsjRb3Aw)

## C# .NET, 9 bytes

```java
n=>n|1>>n
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##NY2xCsIwGIT3PsXRKSG22MHF2iyCk50cXFxqTOGH@keaVBDts8counzL3XdnfGHcaKMZOu/RPjPAhy6QweHhg72Wu4nNhjgskKDRo0HkRvOr0ppjnSXhNp2HJPy8u6ML2o5YyM8a0LtRJBfUFKsatKmWiUrJb4j/z9axd4MtjyMFuye2glS@PoVc9YKkrFN7zub4Bg)

Different approach (and 1 byte shorter) than the existing Java/C# .NET answers. (Also works with negative inputs.)

**Explanation:**

```java
i->       // Method with integer as both parameter and return-type
  i|      //  Return the input bit-wise OR-ed with:
    1>>i  //  1 bit-wise right-shifted by the input
```

`1>>i` will be `1` when the input is 0, and `0` for every other input.
`0|1` for input 0 will therefore result in `1`, and `n|0` for every other input will therefore result in `n`.

Comment: See? You're getting better at bitwise operations ;-)

Comment: These two are also polyglots with Kotlin, Scala, and a ton of other languages :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 13 bytes

```sh
<<<$[$1?$1:1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@ekZmTqlCUmpiikJOZl2qtkJKvUJxaoqCrq6ACEvhvY2OjEq1iaK9iaGUY@z8lHyhkwGUAREZchlyGQIaRsREXAA)

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 15 bytes

```bash
echo $[$1?$1:1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvhfnpGZk6pQlJqYopCTmZdqrZCSr1CcWqKgq6ugAhL4n5qcka@gEq1iaK9iaGUY@z8lHyhowGUAREZchlyGQIaRsREXAA)

## [Dash](https://wiki.debian.org/Shell) (or other POSIX-compliant shell), 17 bytes

```sh
echo $(($1?$1:1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0kszvhfnpGZk6pQlJqYopCTmZdqrZCSr1CcWqKgq6ugAhL4n5qcka@goqGhYmivYmhlqKn5PyUfKGzAZQBERlyGXIZAhpGxERcA)

Answer (score 3):

## Binary Lambda Calculus, 2.125 Bytes

```
00010110 00110001 0
```

Translation into lambda calculus:

```
\n. n (\x. n) (\x. x)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 6 bytes

```
?"1
@!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/fXsmQy0Hx/38DAA)

```
?   Take number input and push it
"   No-op, but a 3-way junction:
    If top is 0, go straight
1     Convert the 0 to 1 and bounce off the dead end
"     Enter the junction again, turn right (reflected to south)
!@    Pop and print as number, turn around the corner and halt

    Otherwise, top is positive; turn right
!@    Pop and print as number and halt
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
¬+
```

Straightforward answer:

```
¬  # nots the input (x == 0 ? 1 : 0)
+  # adds it to the input
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C2%AC%2B&inputs=0&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 3):

## Lolwho.Cares, 62 bytes

```
*2*+21*1*+21010,**>*2+00210`v
0 ^02210012+*1*<  ^<0210002<<
321
```

Old version:

```
*2*+210*1*+210101,**>*2+00210`v
0 ^ 102210012+*1*<  ^<0210002<<
253
```

The last line isn't code; it's the input number.

Online interpreter: https://valthe.scheffers.net/testing/lolwhocares

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20861/welcome-to-code-golf-and-coding-challenges-stack-exchange), and nice first answer! Thanks for linking to an interpreter too! Lolwho.cares looks like an interesting fungeoid (if it is a fungeoid).

Comment: I looked at the definition, it's probably a fungoid.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 8 bytes

Beaten to the shortest solution (as usual!), so here's an alternative.

```
n=>n?n:1
```

### Try It

```js
f=
n=>n?n:1
console.log(f(0))
console.log(f(1))
console.log(f(8888))
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 11 Bytes

```php
<?=$argn?:1;
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/28ceaa84c91fb78b198b2c87e9465616630dd81f)

Answer (score 2):

## Binary-Encoded [Golfical](https://github.com/SuperJedi224/Golfical), 12 bytes

This binary encoding can be converted back to the standard graphical representation using the encoder provided in the Golfical github repo, or run directly using the interpreter by adding the `-x` flag.

Hexdump of binary encoding:

```
00 40 02 15 17 14 00 01 23 1D 17 14
```

Original image:

[image]

Magnified 120x, with color labels:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
o1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@59v@F/XtMj0cPujpjX/AQ)

An alternative to the other Jelly solution. `o` provides a default value for a zero/empty argument; in this case, we default it to 1.

Comment: And another alternative is `»1`

Comment: Now you're making me wonder if it's possible in 1 byte; I doubt it, but you have to wonder. The closest I've got is `ḃ`, which outputs the number itself for all nonzero numbers, and nothing if the input is 0.

Comment: Yeah, another close one is `m` which yields `[0,0]` for `0` and `n` for `n`.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 5, 10 +1 byte for `-p` flag = 11 bytes

```
$_=$_*1||1
```

Run with `-p` flag.

Comment: `$_=$_||1` and thus `$_||=1` is sufficient

Comment: Also, [the other answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118454/3324) don't include the costs of outputting the result, so no need to count `-p`.

Comment: You are mistaken. Zero is false, whether stored as a number or as a string. However, if you populate `$_` using `echo 0 | perl -pe'...'`, you actually have `"0\n"`, which is true. `-l` would take care of that.

Comment: @ikegami we consider here that requiring the input to be supplied without trailing newline is valid. (using `echo -n ...`  for instance). Regarding the cost of outputting the result, the rules on PPCG say that the result need to be either printed, or returned by a function (which is what does the answer you linked), or returned some other way (I don't remember all valid options). (so counting `-p` flag is mandatory)

Answer (score 2):

## [Whirl](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Whirl/), 38 bytes

```
01100011100011110011111100001000111100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/whirl#@29gaGhgACSgpCGEBHMNEGL//xsAAA)

Explanation:

```
01100     op.ccw, op.intio    Mem1 = STDIN
011100    math.ccw, math.=    If (Mem1 = 0) Then (Math.Val = 1) Else (Math.Val = 0)
0111100   op.cw, op.one       Op.Val=1
11111100  math.add            Math.Val = Math.Val + Mem1
00        op.one              Op.Val=1 (Cheapest way to loop back to the Math wheel)
100       math.store          Mem1 = Math.Val
0111100   op.ccw, op.intio    STDOUT = Mem1
```

Answer (score 2):

## k, 2 bytes

```
1|
```

Finds the maximum of 1 and whatever number is given.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/#QOTVX)

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/), 10 bytes

Improvement suggested by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow).

```
f(x)=0^x+x
```

Previous 13-byte solution:

```
f(x)=max(1,x)
```

Try it [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wyqb0cjrd7)

Comment: Desmos tips: you can have lists of integers like [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/w63e2vuz84).

Comment: 10 bytes: `f(x)=0^x+x`. This works because 0^0 equals 1 in Desmos.

Comment: @AidenChow That's wild. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Yea, this `0^x+x` trick is actually used to avoid `log(0)` situations when trying to count the digits of a number. `floor(logn)+1` (where `n` is the number we are trying to get the digits of) works if `n` is positive, but the shortest way to cover the `n=0` case seems to be `floor(log(0^n+n))+1`.

Answer (score 2):

### C (gcc), 11 bytes

```
f(n){n?:1;}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S9YtSU7@/z9NI0@zOs/eytC6losrNzEzT0OTq5qLs6AoM68kTUNJNUVHQTUlJk9JRyFNw0ATRJppalpz1f7/DwA)

Comment: I tried it online with the provided link, and it outputs `0, 6`.

Comment: It seems they've changed the gcc behavior recently. If you switch to tcc it still works.

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-hr` 4 bytes

```
:0=+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fysBW@/9/y/@6GUUA)

## Explanation

```
:     # Take 2 inputs
  0=  # Check whether the input is 0
      # (Yields 1 if the input is 0)
      # (Yields 0 otherwise)
    + # Add the input with this result and print it rawly
      # i.e. 0->1, 5->5
```

Comment: 4 bytes: `:0=+`

Comment: The "**H**ighly**R**adioactive" interpreter flag.

Answer (score 2):

## GolfScript, <s>4</s> 3* bytes

```
~1|
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v86w5v9/AwA)

*thanks to user [a'_'](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85052/a)

Comment: Using a bitwise or would [still work](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v86w5v9/YwA).

Answer (score 2):

## [convey](http://xn--wxa.land/convey/), 6 bytes

```
{+1
}.
```

[Try it online!](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoieysxXG59LiIsInYiOjEsImkiOiIwIn0=)

Outputs the max of the input and `1`. I think this is the optimal answer, since to use any binary function, there must be a second line with at least two characters.

You can also do the more traditional `x+!x` for [8 bytes](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoie1wiPTBcbn0rPCIsInYiOjEsImkiOiIwIn0=).

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 16 bytes

```python
lambda x:x+(x<1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fpmCrEPM/JzE3KSVRocKqQlujwtbWQPN/QVFmXolGmoaBpiYXjG2oqfkfAA)

Thanks caird coinheringaahing for saving an extra byte!

Comment: Welcome to CGCC. I think you can test for `x<1` to save a byte: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqkJbo8LGUPN/QVFmXolGmoaBpuZ/AA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 8 bytes

```
$0||$0=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fxaCmRsXA1vD/f0MuI2NTLktLLgMuIwA)

Slightly different approach to [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/118444/stay-away-from-zero/118478#118478), reducing 2 bytes.

```
$0||$0=1      Basically, an OR logic gate. Right part is not considered if the left one is true.
              $0 is the input, parsed as true if different from zero, printing the input.
              If input is zero, $0 is set to 1 (right part).
              As $0 becomes 1, it is parsed true, and then the input is printed.
```

Answer (score 2):

## RegEx, 3 Bytes

Match pattern (2 Bytes):

```
^0
```

Substitution pattern (1 Byte):

```
1
```

Takes input as string without any leading zeros and substitutes it for 1 if it is 0.

[Try on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JOpnEH/2)

Answer (score 1):

## C, 27 Bytes

```
f(n){printf("%d\n",n?n:1);}
```

Comment: You don't have to output, you can return that too. Also in GCC, you can do `n?:1`.

Comment: @betseg thanks I like that n?:1 trick

Comment: In this particular case you can also use `n||1` which is compiler-independent, or `!n+n` as seen in several other answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 3 bytes

```
t~+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@19Sp/3/vwEA)

#### Explanation

```
t   % Implicit inupt. Duplicate
~   % Logical negation. Converts zero to 1, and nonzero to 0
+   % Add. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, <s>24</s> <s>22</s> 17 Bytes

#### blatantly stolen from [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118454/59735)

```ps
!($a=$args[0])+$a
```

Explanation

```
Invert the value, returning 0 for non-0 numbers, and 1 for 0, then add the intitial to it.

this makes it basically 1/0 + value, so for 0 the first value is 1, any other numbers it's 0.

examples:
# !0+0 = 1
# !1+1 = 1
# !9+9 = 9
```

Comment: Could you instead use `!$a` as your index check? You wouldn't be able to set `$a` in your current manner, but I think something like this would work? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@6@hoZJoq5JYlF4cbRCrqWOoGa2okhj7//9/AwA "PowerShell – TIO Nexus")

Comment: @Sinusoid that worked perfectly for -2, but turns out the C answer was a bit ahead of us both, didn't think of the method at all.

Comment: That is certainly interesting! I will need to keep this method in mind :P

Answer (score 1):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 11 bytes

```
/#0/1//#//#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/slashes#@6@vbKBvqK@vDET//wMA)

Since there is no other way to take input in ///, hard-code the input after the last `#`.

Works by replacing `#0` with 1. Then it removes any remaining `#`. The `#` makes sure that an input of `10` would not output `11`.

Version that takes input in [Itflabtijtslwi](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Itflabtijtslwi):

```
GGaGGGGbGG/#0/1//#//#ab
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl5#fY5Ba8JAEIXv/goXB9wR67g9dg3SUrukSKE04KGrEpOtCaRG3EApafqvPadLUhCsdBjmMPPeNw/W3mTSnz3dr/3gYX57F/iPwct84fdllOR7WSsVKlcbpag3JkHUcx1u6r@OzkeSZoYLLNM3btlKKc6nN68r0nr5pfUIB1NUijGL5ftnB6wHQrr5bZ2Aj5BA0NZKiL2tKSKOssVZchD9DFbPnCQmLKvKZLZ9wVt6M9VygIx180PXHRpi82p/SHcFB4HyZKPzYHhh8xuUgx1CjJ5DDOEaLyc@2/yb3JRZaAtZVbUYH3f5VRRGifkB)

Comment: For your second program, the input has to be less than 100. Maybe you should mention this?

Comment: @boboquack Yes.

Answer (score 1):

### Ohm, <s>11</s> 6 bytes

```
ö?┼¿1;
```

Uses `CP-437` character encoding. Run with `-c` flag

Explanation:

```
ö?┼¿1;
       ■print(                                            )
  ┼    ■      first_input()
 ?   ; ■                   if(                     )
ö      ■                      int(first_input())!=0
   ¿   ■                                            else 
    1  ■                                                 1
```

Comment: Here's a list of things you could fix: (1) if you just _say_ this is in CP437 (no need for the `-c` flag), you only need to count characters. (2) Ohm is written in Ruby, so `0` is a truthy value. However, there is a built-in `x != 0` component (`ö`). (3) There is implicit printing, so `,` is not necessary. (4) Ohm is on [TIO](https://tio.run/nexus/ohm "Ohm – TIO Nexus") now, so it'd help if you added a link to it.

Comment: FYI, feel free to ping me in chat if you have any questions about/feature reqs for the language!

Comment: Again, there's no need for the `-c` flag. That's just for reading files; it's not necessary for PPCG submissions. Just say it's in CP437 and you're good.

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 10 bytes

```
!$0{$0=1}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/awk#@6@oYlCtYmBrWGv4/78hlxGXAZcxlwmXKZcZlzmXBZcllyUQAAA)

Example Usage:

```
awk '!$0{$0=1}1' <<< 978
```

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, 12 bytes

```
#(get[1]% %)
```

The `get` function takes an associative data structure, a key, and a default value. Vectors are associative using sequential position as the key. So, `[1]` is a vector with the value 1 at position 0. If `get` is called with parameter 0 it will return 1, otherwise no other keys exist in the vector so it returns the default value of the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

## [Universal lambda](http://www.golfscript.com/lam/), 3 bytes (17 bits)

```
00010110001100010
```

It is a function and not a complete program. I think it should work, but didn't actually test it because it doesn't seem easy to do so. It means λx.x(λy.x)(λy.y).

## Lazy K, 10 bytes

```
S(SIK)(KI)
```

It is a function, untested, too.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
D0›i,}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@@9i8KhhV6ZOrcH//8YA)

```
D           //push two inputs (implicit)
 0›         //push input greater than zero
   i        //if true
    ,}      //print input
      1     //push 1. printing is implicit if there is no previous output
```

Comment: I'm sure there is a much shorter way to do this...

Comment: Me too, but I can't *actually* work 05ab1e, so...

Comment: You could save 3 bytes with `D_i1`.

Comment: Or in two bytes: `$M`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 14 bytes

```
((){{}[()]}{})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@69RXV0braEZW6uhWV2r@f@/KQA)

Just computes: `1 + (n ? n-1 : 0)`.

Comment: [Challenge accepted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118452/31716) :)

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 29 bytes

[**Try Online**](http://ideone.com/nDPwpz)

```java
int f(int n){return n<1?1:n;}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Starry](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Starry), 14 bytes

```
, +'      +*`.
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/starry#@6@joK2uAAbaWgl6//8bAAA)

#### Explanation

Space shown as `_` .

```
,           Read integer and push to stack
_+          Duplicate
'           If non-zero jump to branch label
______+     Push 1
*           Add
`           Mark branch label
.           Print as a number
```

Comment: My first Starry answer

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 bytes

```
w1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@19u@P@/AQA)

Returns the larger of 1 and the input.

Answer (score 1):

### C++, 22 bytes

```
[](int i){return!i+i;}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/cpp-gcc#JUxLCsMgFFz7TvHabhQ3WZaouUjpQqLCg0TB6Crk7FabxXyYGaa9KK5bdR41paNkb/cFgGLB3VLkAk5gtpaEwXy@fOQkzuxLzfFBktSlgIWU8a7MpJD0u5OUAhg7ipvnNdWCWiMNeqLp6CZwEkP/Ex/d1o/uX5wUXK39AA)

Answer (score 1):

### Excel, 10 bytes

```
=MAX(A1,1)
```

Here's another 10-byte solution: [link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118527/55372)

Answer (score 1):

### C#, 11 bytes

```c#
n=>n<1?1:n;
```

This compiles to a `Func<int, int>`.

Answer (score 1):

## SpecBAS - 20 bytes

```
1 INPUT n: ?n OR n=0
```

`?` is shorthand for `PRINT`

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, 10  bytes

```
#(max 1%)
```

Not much to explain.

Comment: I think you can shorten this to `#(max 1%)` (9 bytes). https://tio.run/nexus/clojure#0@DKSS1RiM7Lr0otyv@vrJGbWKFgqKr5P5ZLo6AoM68kJ09BAyKpYKCpiSloiE3QCCio@R8A

Answer (score 1):

## [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip), <del>20</del> 18 bytes

```
eaABb
*`\\-!
fcCDd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87ILPj/PzXR0SmJSyshJkZXkSst2dkl5f9/AwA)

#### How?

```
 aABb
            Copy the low 4 bits from input to output
 cCDd
```

---

```
e
*           Set the higher bits of output, so that the values are ASCII digits
f
```

---

```
eaABb
*           Replicate any ASCII digits on input to output
fcCDd
```

---

```
            -
     !      Produce a high signal, but only during the first byte
            -
```

---

```
 aAB
 `\\-*      Set the lowest bit of output, if the four low bits of input are unset
  CD
```

---

```
 aAB        Set the lowest bit of output, if the four low bits
 `\\-!      of input are unset, and only on the first byte
  CD
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/L3viathan/Aceto), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
rid0=`1p
```

`r`ead an `i`nteger and `d`uplicate it, then push `0`. Are they `=`? Then (`` ` ``) push a `1`. `p`rint the top element.

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
f(n)=n<1?1:n
```

<s>Unfortunately, Julia doesn't do implicit casting from int to bool, so I have to burn an entire 3 characters just to do a comparison to zero.</s> Saved one byte by safely assuming the number isn't negative. Still too verbose for my taste, though.

Comment: You can post the answer as an anonymous function and save 2 bytes, `n->n<1?1:n` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@5@mYKvwP0/XLs/G0N7QKu9/QVFmXklOnp6GRpqGoYGmjkKahjGYNNDU1PwPAA "Julia 0.6 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

### Python 21 Bytes

```py
int(max('1',input()))
```

Takes input from REPL environment

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 7 bytes

```
{it?:1}
```

Elvis operator; if true, return self, else return 1. Only false integer value auto-unboxxed to false in Groovy is 0. Thusly, exactly the spec.

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), <s>49</s> <s>47</s> 36 bytes

```
	N =INPUT
	N =EQ(N) 1
	OUTPUT =N
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9NPwdbTLyA0hAvEcg3U8NNUMOTi9A8NAYop2Ppxufq5/P9vAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Symbolic Python](https://github.com/FTcode/Symbolic-Python), 11 bytes

```
_+=_==(_>_)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K67MTcrPyUzWLagsycjP@/8/Xts23tZWI94uXvP///@mAA)

```
_+=           # Output = Input +
   _==(_>_)                       Input == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets, 9 Bytes

Anonymous worksheet function that takes input from range `A1` and outputs to the calling cell

```
=Max(1,A1
```

Comment: This look very cool mate :)

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, 43 bytes

```bash
if [ $1 -eq 0 ];then echo 1;else echo $1;fi
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 10 bytes

```julia
x->x<1?1:x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@59mm5Sanpn3v0LXrsLG0N7QquJ/al4Kl0NxRn65QpqehoGVpeZ/AA)

Comment: also 10 bytes: `x->x+(x<1)`

Answer (score 1):

## [BitCycle](https://github.com/dloscutoff/esolangs/tree/master/BitCycle) `-u`, <s>8</s> <s>7</s> 4 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)*

```
?/1!
```

[Try it here!](https://dloscutoff.github.io/Esolangs/BitCycle/?p=qj1b&i=NA__&f=1)

#### How it works

The `-u` flag converts decimal inputs to unary and unary outputs to decimal. Inputs emerge from the source `?` moving east.

- For positive numbers, the splitter `/` sends one bit northward, off the playfield, while the other bits continue straight through. The `1` bit that started on the playfield, plus all but one of the input bits, land in the sink `!`, which therefore outputs the same number that was input (or more specifically, `n-1+1`).
- For zero, there are no input bits, the splitter does nothing, and the `1` bit that started on the playfield lands in the sink and outputs `1`.

Answer (score 1):

## [*Acc!!*](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!), <s>75</s> <s>72</s> 41 bytes

```
N
_+48/_
Count i while _/48 {
Write _
N
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/9@PK17bxEI/nss5vzSvRCFToTwjMydVIV7fxEKhmiu8KLMEyOHy46r9/9/QwBQA)

#### Explanation

`N` reads a character and stores its ASCII code into the accumulator.

Since the first character will always be a digit, the accumulator's value is between 48 and 57. If the accumulator is exactly 48, `48/_` will be 1; otherwise, it will be 0. We add this value to the accumulator. In effect: if the first digit of the number was 0, we consider it as 1; otherwise, we leave it unchanged.

We then enter a loop that writes the accumulator out as a character, reads another character into the accumulator, and loops until the ASCII code we read is less than 48 (probably 10 for newline). Then we halt.

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 6 bytes

```
:?!1n;
```

Could have been 1 byte shorter if `?` had the opposite conditional behaviour.

```
:?       check if nonzero, then either
  !      a) skip the next instruction or
   1     b) push 1 to the stack
    n    print
     ;   terminate
```

Comment: Take the input via the `-v` flag instead. It saves a byte, and it's less suspect than using the char code of a character

Comment: [5 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38pQQzvv////umUGAA)

Comment: Terminating with an error wasn't legal when I used to be around.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 10 bytes

```javascript
n=>n&&n||1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9s@z/P1i5PTS2vpsbwf1p@kUZZYpFCpq2BtUKmja0hiNLW1uRSUEjOzyvOz0nVy8lP18jUSdbI1NT8DwA)

here is one more

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 8 bytes

```javascript
n=>n?n:1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9s@z/P1i7PPs/K8H9afpFGWWKRQqatgbVCpo2tIYjS1tbkUlBIzs8rzs9J1cvJT9fI1EnWyNTU/A8A)

and lastly

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 7 bytes

```javascript
n=>n||1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9s@z/P1i6vpsbwf1p@kUZZYpFCpq2BtUKmja0hiNLW1uRSUEjOzyvOz0nVy8lP18jUSdbI1NT8DwA)

Comment: From the BASIC answer `n=>n+!n` (also 7 bytes) should also work ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Sed, 7 bytes

Input in any number base, without any leading zeros.  (It doesn't even need to be a consistent base!)

```
s/^0/1/
```

0 is the only number that begins with `0`; just change that to `1`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Triangular](https://github.com/aaronryank/triangular), 6 bytes

```
$,w%1<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLPr/X0WnXNXQ5v9/AwA)

Ungolfed:

```
  $
 , w
% 1 <
-----------------------
$              Read from input as an integer
 w,            Change directions if ToS != 0 (will go straight to print)
   <1          Push 1
     %         Print ToS as an integer
```

Answer (score 1):

### [W](https://github.com/a-ee/w), 2 bytes

```
1|
```

### Explanation

```
a   # Take an input
 1| # Logical or with 1
    # If n is 0, this evaluates to 1
    # It evaluates to 0 otherwise
```

Answer (score 1):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), 70 bytes

```
2a2x1v4a8m2x2v1x1f1r3x2v2e1o3f0x1x2f1a1o0x1x3f1r3x1v4e1o3f0x1x4f0a0x1f
```

Works for any input integer, provided it's passed as a file terminated with the control character STX (U+0002).

**Explanation** (with `0x` commands removed)

```
2a2x1v           # Set variable 1 equal to 2
4a8m2x2v         # Set variable 2 equal to 48 ("0")
1x1f1r3x2v2e1o3f # Function 1
                 # Read a byte of input
                 # Jump to function 2 if it equals variable 2
                 # Otherwise, output it and jump to function 3
1x2f1a1o         # Function 2
                 # Add 1 to the register and output
1x3f1r3x1v4e1o3f # Function 3
                 # Read a byte of input
                 # Jump to function 4 if it equals variable 1
                 # Otherwise, output it and jump back to the start of function 3
1x4f0a           # Function 4
                 # Add 0 to the register
1f               # Call function 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Flurry](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flurry), 12 bytes

```
({})[(){}]{}
```

#### Run example

```
$ ./flurry -nin -c "({})[(){}]{}" 0
1
$ ./flurry -nin -c "({})[(){}]{}" 1
1
$ ./flurry -nin -c "({})[(){}]{}" 2
2
$ ./flurry -nin -c "({})[(){}]{}" 10
10
```

For single input `n`, computes `n (K n) 1`: apply "a constant function that returns `n` regardless of argument" `n` times to the number 1.

```
({})    Pop n and push n
[(){}]  Apply (K n); n is popped again from the stack
{}      Apply I (equivalent to number 1); popping from empty stack gives I
```

Reduction into SKI terms don't help much:

```
n (K n) 1
= I n (K n) 1
= S I K n 1
which translates into <>{{}}(){}{}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 24 bytes

```
listen to N
say N-0 or 1
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
┌+
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///RlB7t//91DQ24dI25jLgMuQyA2IjLmMvQAAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
┌   # Inverted boolean the (implicit) input-integer (1 if 0; 0 for any other integer)
 +  # Add this to the (implicit) input-integer
    # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## ARM Thumb-2 machine code, 6 bytes

Machine code:

```
b900 3001 4770
```

Assembly:

```c
        .syntax unified
        .arch armv6t2
        .thumb
        .globl no_zero
        .thumb_func
no_zero:
        // skip next insn if r0 != 0
        cbnz    r0, .Ldont_add_1
.Ladd_1:
        // increment r0
        adds    r0, #1
.Ldont_add_1:
        // Return
        bx      lr
```

It doesn't get much simpler than that.

Input is in `r0`, output is in `r0`, follows standard calling convention.

## ARM Thumb-2 machine code, branch/IT-less, 8 bytes

Only works for non-negative numbers unlike the branching solution.

Machine code:

```
4241 f140 0000 4770
```

Assembly:

```c
        .syntax unified
        .arch armv6t2
        .thumb
        .globl no_zero_branchless
        .thumb_func
no_zero_branchless:
        // Negate r0 into r1. We only care about
        // setting the flags here.
        negs    r1, r0
        // Add the carry flag to r0. (wide insn)
        adc     r0, r0, #0
        // Return
        bx      lr
```

Follows the same calling convention.

`negs` follows the same rules as `subs` for setting flags. So, if `r0` was positive, the result would have a borrow, but if it was `0`, it would not.

Then, we just add with carry against zero to add `1` if `r0` was zero, or `0` if `r0` was positive.

Yes, you read that correctly.

When subtracting, ARM *clears* the carry flag to indicate a borrow. It is counterintuitive and usually annoying when golfing.

But I decided to use this for a small challenge.

Unfortunately, `adc` doesn't have a narrow immediate form, so we either have to waste another register to set it to zero, or use a wide instruction.

Answer (score 1):

## [BRASCA](https://github.com/sjoerdpennings/brasca), <s>14</s> 7 bytes

```
ig:0=+n
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##zVt7c9s2Ev9fnwK1r5VUS7bsJE3is9zaSXp128QZ253rjcdlIRGSmJIEQ4KWPX189dwu@BBBQiIYPz3TxiaB3d8@sQCWwbWYcf/JiyD85HgBDwWJrqMe8aiYtSYh94hwPEayVy5jQfI4pL4N/6Qv8C/4b8pa6QMR0jEb0fEfrdbYpVFEDkMajekr/H23ReBnbW3tVMCAHgnZ1IkECyMCVMglDR06clkEA@RAm02IZTm@IyyrEzF30t1tyRf4sy5pyIk5mfwlDt6M5IAhOb9Qn1N4NlAfjZRHCx4HISNzBgyo7fhTwi5ZCFrDX2lExjMKsiLfb8uMQxhiedxmQPd76kasgPu9EzC77/jEpoLmj50J8bk0AUwHZptORIW47nR38yEF@jDAwulAfjEDUXa657u7/e0LZdKEh8TqEYsAU@bHHgupYJ0SqRIjDTO0VxS7Apmqb86RZa/ytIxDtcwmDQLm2x0e2p2EcLebD2egszrJwUsWWv2BohOlxhkx5pMAjCCYTa6ZKNmHuqiqaysbUbXR2cyJyNxxXRIJDj5A4TcxY2QEBv@DCRLwyBEO90seN585LrNczoMIiP75t0KRkTE6BDoskgo4Mg9VAjjCSt9UvXScOFRRbvkcIs91xhAlYNtcGP0IwQNV3PX3cTQjMHEEHAWX0KR58ggMYICVDJA@08PRBW@pWhTfF6lfUjdmhE8WEYOcNFzwfcoDf13JBN1GDuouF2TEhYBUBZxXimUl4@qkc/yIhaIzSIbUC2iEAGeo/JdLvgBQFR7sKrNziQUPssRZTjQ5WTXMQibi0C94XjUS0yEFYMgmid0SmloV8KAo/D3AHGQaO4UwRkDZ4pFjipiwsoepSbI/VXzZUzKEmKRrmnRFs1S5UFCCtTx7pJs9qs4u@FwReztKXVAbwJjsbksiJQQTGbt6uQdNxa2SHnX1ShmkJjzB9ThiWpHlm7JTFfhkI7o5LektSMpl/lTM9A6bvCvTTV0NXnYWLAqhGbuw4EpqcoUguEIQF/RBOuV1o5uzGsWOaycPy/wE8wK1sMEnFtQdSs2hvoSF0WUfYy6YYh0sDrLlDJIP9zxcoaqVAi4@pRoBzFohvU8G1UKiMqo/JNvKKOkjVZzD5dRKspaBZYKgu52vJauuMi@dqCefuWGmmG4VbJHBRSMG4B0hFlGSkZoZllUT53LOBUzKENVPyUbiLDl9tQzttVpNn4Uxq7ftkOys5vR7Y3MUh1VAmNLHifXkU29q4R7k9BoylkdoOIVI8AVsXwK5Z8IyELY0m8E1mZC9Cajcpx7br74dkz0Mm/1W64xDPOHmBkJ7FE97JIa8NbG3xhhqwIXamG8mW@NNHBq5fE5sPvcJj0UQi3R4tDWOJDAH90XI07KkxJblUaiLrdSECQAwRGHrlTpZii2vJNc@OdPdwXDD/5TuzJKcRQ4x@STZEHOVR4Pi9GJqytIceQsQ5Gj5d5LoCuzysnZP5snCm2JiC69VE@V2LZI615C9KCeAdIyyF1vqZJUH60QusnuQA/fVYnVFnhloQqigtWIhPajGfMWPt83JbRuQ2zEnt2NA7ok5uScG5J6ak3tqQO6ZOblnBuS@MSf3jQG55@bknhuQe2FO7oUBuZfm5F4akHMbuLFJWPzcgJ6J57EGcWFi3DcNAsMk0OwGkWFi3tcNfNkkNmYN3MXEm39o4i8mDvNTI4ImFP9c2yXrr9k4ZFgXmBLPHmHF1zfJ2H8jmyP/Bmw2TNiEyEYudyfyIFfHhy5WYH3FKsGYDML9hoP7C3lq3Bn1CAWUegstkdDptqoLthQgWe2hTprRsFbw9u/tlY6hHuNqi1@jKroshTzlqilnNrYvuqsIKRXVBu6mqhp5S3EXG@AejhfOxpdi30A/OLDtO3YAnctuUAM/7SO@03iENwziAUD2TUB@jSDfxq5wAvf6AUB@bQJyK0ksgk3Be2zn0ol0O8q7B7u1ZYL2S6lSbscufwCMX5pA/A0hvrkKuL8sUd@x1Y3MHskA@hjeBGGVOV4Ybk5g45f@GgGDDu12dUn60BFzB7ayDbLSPwj63fHZrWL@x0RdX8l8@O71A9jzKxN8fyG@45MHgPeXCTwL4f36IPh@A3wa7zvVbuIrwCkCD@QZO1@cWx@sLBWKdwZAwEA9Iy2XQ3MuIxMuB5JLdh1jJox6X2AmzaGez2EDPkby9JBPena/5FBG4ZAd8tcS3kXCdozXpPKsHkThkxUcPjfz0JuMrKD@t4p6cdVmCjy7fTNFlY2ntzChIo2H0nj8UlU/xkdCRMsyufj6LGNk2CQJA3xvc3wlRct7t/Tgsx5fU50b4wtq9Ed82dMT6f3C47EvTHdw/mIHN@glU1fs4YxtdDt2el9jp0ekh9W@cEN/@FYmy6RdK22MGPS3d56b@l3e29WBfWb5XKFrAOCLfI1b3KnWJm3NWUZ662rC8l/IMprTQBpazDlxBPMiwv0bJ/M7z/gjA/lOpE25yBYpMQsZu18Zx3euiPFNVKa9z6no8RT1OOY@rpt@rkxwl4RwdP9@gjEWCRRpA/@hRhE2LYux3AHSpgFk025vfuCOL9n53UUiyw@@sH1hedIbY5qDZFJIfYUrvXR2/YleE@UgeAN1OKk6oOwTBIg4Dqb8NPd1@rrzcUWoXpqilfYHRa7lYgGUZPL@kDx9kXa04t97Q/Ls@fJ5yokjsDiXSPDWXk4H0PVyHxXlXvTAJRrobNyb3ANV7JefLTVAbtWLfSXLXweIhHZ9yb7S7yq0fy3SNimsTRb1CpcYufzi90@1JH3TMkQ27CTR3OwkHZKBbZJnfklxTpfiLOaUqySnXFVySqvODdSuptsWU3MmcLR1bOBoXB61yF4M7Pw@OH11dJR2ONZ53aIVodJ2vLQdoSRKtV9ZexmBP3JIZzxTr4G6PQhre9huG1j6eKmoJkHw8NLmwddEaF8VOs2gj9fAReM2EPPdcjEfq3E1hl0IrInnV9wXIXfJ9y6f1ytkDxXyM4siqKPpXd@AoPr2aKPEta2nxExU3bTdaB918R8wj2xfvx917D9edQzllc7HGNz6HhQxHD5aTbT/1wZNHDIxZ8x/DFtL1BdWl2P83@N1oO/Qgc5Y6Dm4MWvdTlLEr73YlSNMast1BAD50JZtwNQlH2IvqEnsUuuo10GtPqotCLWIPiCiHwEFVnNzKKyjJj0Oav9MPbcfc274OWIzdn2V3YYBu3Nk919se@3Lntlqz3VV3UnN@wUWvSs3WMpOqb99UWOhZVLlQhX7xGubabXSXpSkhSX5rmTdv1NRTTzp1equntL3d2adQmeGNJMv9iTNlrpzSb5PkVIEIZMHMlH@qSp@Dpm2Q1W75fW90foG@fUz/LTFEVAaTsh8xnzY4nNgHMqoEg7YFNhOYPdu1/RHN@u3Uj9hydEcI2vZQyDPlR3RMk/mlSasFFypU2H9rbxCyT7YLH@oaZQC2dWYBYL8xK5HHBIP9tqEYRyI0ndP1WyeTnwj/4G0jYYsibN@yj2WfOg6Z74g85D70x6eBPM5GIcAJ67CTUrptTcnJ8cnu0Q3vXT3mkzIP@XehHTtUWEBuPIhfEGE5DuAo9Rx008XWk03DouxSgiAj2l2GCvveW9wVEmHK6sQDUYMfT3G6maV1u3ZlhDXB@iCNq2S1ZJL9Vklt0LsxiLXi9tc1KVi4s@nnf8D)

-7 bytes by RezNesX

### Explanation

````
<implicit input> - Push STDIN to stack
ig               - Convert numbers from ASCII to number, and concatenate the stack
  :0=            - If the number is zero (pushes 1)
     +n          - Add and print as number.

```
````

Comment: 7 bytes: `ig:0=+n`

Answer (score 1):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), 12 bytes (content).

Unprintable characters are escaped.

```
.c\001.y.s\001.d.a
```

### Usage

- Expects stack has only an item, as an argument.
- Stack content: (n, xxx) to (n', xxx, n, xxx).

### Usage example

Filename to be `_.e.n`, with your input from stdin.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 19 bytes

```python
lambda n:[n,1][n<1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PycxNyklUSHPKjpPxzA2Os/GMPb/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## APOL, 8 bytes

`¿(⧣ ⋔ 1)`

### Explanation

```
¿(   Returning if statement
  ⧣    Integer input (condition, 0 evaluates to false)
  ⋔    If item (returns the value of the condition, executed if true)
  1    A literal 1 (executed if false)
)
Implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
¬[1
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLCrFsxIiwiIiwiMTIiXQ==)

Explanation:

```
# implict input
 ¬  # logical not
  [1  # 1 if truthy else the original input
# implict output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Aussie++](https://github.com/zackradisic/aussieplusplus), 60 bytes

```
THE HARD YAKKA FOR f IS(x)<YA RECKON x ==0?<BAIL 1;>BAIL x;>
```

All whitespace is mandatory. Tested in commit `9522366`, where all numbers are truthy (see [this issue](https://github.com/zackradisic/aussieplusplus/issues/37)), so I can't just say `BAIL x ||1;`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 bytes

```
1|
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWiwxrlhQnJRdDuQsWGkAYAA) Logical OR with 1.

**Alternative:**

```
1§
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWiw0PLV9SnJRcDOUvWGgAYQAA) Maximum of input and 1.

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 2 bytes

```
1M
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FosMfZcUJyUXQ7kLVhtwGXIZcRlzmXCZQoQA)

Max with 1.

Answer (score 1):

## Commodore BASIC (CBM/PET, VIC-20, Commodore C64, Commodore C16/+4) 19 BASIC tokens, 17 PETSCII characters with keyword abbreviations

```
0INPUTN:?N+-(N=.)
```

Very simple, in Commodore [early Microsoft] BASIC, if you do like `PRINT X=Y` it will return `-1` if true, or `0` if false. A single equals is used for comparison and assignment, and the context is picked up by the interpreter.

We ask for a number with the `INPUT` keyword, which will enter a numeric value into the variable `N`. So we will then `PRINT` N plus a negative of the returned value of `N=.` with the `.` being a more performant replacement for `0` in this instance (a very trivial optimisation for such a short program). When N is 0, it adds --1, which just adds 1. When it is not zero, then we add -0 which is zero.

[image: Stay Away from Zero on the CBM PET]

Answer (score 1):

## [R 4.1+](https://www.r-project.org), 8 bytes

```r
\(n)n+!n
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhYrYjTyNPO0FfMg3LXFiQUFOZUaBlbmOmmaELEFCyA0AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 5 bytes

```
ri1e>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@1@UaZhq9/@/AQA)

#### Explanation

```
ri   e# Read input as an integer
1    e# Push 1
e>   e# Maximum. Implictly display
```

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 17 bytes

```
@cmd/cset/a%1+!%1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Math++](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Math%2B%2B), 3 bytes

```
?|1
```

("Body must be at least 30 characters")

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=36422623#36422623

Answer (score 0):

## [Microscript II](https://github.com/SuperJedi224/Microscript-II/), 4 bytes

```
1sN|
```

Rough translation:

```
x=1
push x
x=readnum()
x|=pop()
```

`x` is then printed implicitly at the end.

Answer (score 0):

## [braingasm](https://github.com/daniero/braingasm), 4 bytes

```
;z+:
```

`;` reads a number from stdin, `z+` increments that number if it is 0, `:` prints.

Answer (score 0):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), <s>11</s> 8 bytes

```
?:-(a>1)
```

Thanks to @l4m2 for saving me some bytes!

**Explanation**:

```
?         PRINT
 :        an integer taken from the cmd line (and store it as 'a')
  -       minus
   (a<1)  -1 if 'a' is less than 1 (can only be 0) or 0 otherwise.
          This leaves any a to be a, but turns zeroes into 1 by double negative.
```

---

Old code, that didn't use the inline `:` yet:

```
:?(a>0)+a+1
```

Explanation

```
:       Get an int from the cmd line, a
?       PRINT
 (a>0)    if a is greater than 0, this is -1, else 0
 +a        yields 0 for 0 and a-1 for >0
 +1        makes 1's for 0 and a's for all other values
```

Comment: can it be `a-(a<1)`?

Answer (score 0):

### CJam, 5 bytes

```
ri1e|
```

Explanation:

```
ri    e# Read token and convert to integer
  1e| e# OR with 0
```

Comment: `|` is bitwise OR, so an input of **2** will result in an output of **3**.

Comment: @Dennis That's true; edited.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 12 bytes

```ruby
->n{n<1?1:n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#S7ON@a9rl1edZ2Nob2iVV/u/oLSkWCEtOj21pFivJD8@M/a/AQA)

---

Alternate version that reads directly from STDIN instead of being a function. Same number of bytes after counting the `-p` flag (11+1 = 12 bytes). Effectively a port of the Retina solution.

```ruby
sub /^0/,?1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#U1YsKk2qVNAt@F9cmqSgH2egr2Nv@P@/AQA)

Comment: Nice, I wanted to post `->x{[x,1].max}`, but your solution is 2 bytes shorter.

Answer (score 0):

## Tcl, 25

```
puts [expr $argv?$argv:1]
```

[demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_tcl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMamlCZ0ZCZ05mems) — How to use: In the green area, type

```
tclsh main.tcl $n
```

where `$n` is the input number. Do not press backspace, otherwise your browser can go back in history!

Answer (score 0):

## [Beam](https://github.com/ETHproductions/beam-js), 40 bytes

This reads the input as a string as it doesn't have any other option.  Basically it checks if the first character is 0 by removing 48 from it.  If 0 increment and output as a number, otherwise output it as a number, then read the rest of the input outputting it as characters.

```
 r'''''>`----\
 :+n++(------/
/<:<
r@
\u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/beam#@69QpA4Cdgm6QBDDpWClnaetraELBvpc@jZWNlxFDlwxpf//GwAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge-98](http://quadium.net/funge/spec98.html), 5 bytes

```
&:!+.
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge-98#@69mpait9/@/AQA) (Warning - will take 60 seconds per test because of how TIO treats `&`)

#### Explanation

```
&:       Push 2 copies of the input
  !      Logical not the 1st copy - i.e. push 1 if 0, push 0 otherwise
   +     Add them together - this results in +0 normally, but +1 in the case of 0
    .    Print that value
         Loops back around to the first command
&        Because there's no more input, the TIO interpreter stalls for a minute and ends.
```

#### [Befunge-93](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Befunge) Variant, 6 bytes

It's trivial to implement Befunge-93 in a similar way, except we can't use the `&` to end the program this time. Thus, the code is 1 byte longer, for **6 bytes**:

```
&:!+.@
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge#@69mpait5/D/vwEA)

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure(Script), 10 bytes

```
#(max 1 %)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Silberjoder](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Silberjoder), 42 bytes

```
0+b1,-CB+b1:BC<. +iB-b1+CB-CA[+CA.,-CA]1
```

How it works:

```
0
```

The first three characters are all data and are not executed. They are a newline (10), a zero (48), and a DC3 (19).

```
+b1
```

Point b at the "0" character. Note that a is still pointing at the newline character.

```
,
```

Read the first character of input.

```
-CB
```

Subtract what b is pointing to (the "0") from the first digit.

```
+b1
```

Point b at the DC3 character, which has value 19

```
:BC
```

Jump to position 19+3=22 if the c is pointing to anything other than zero. This would happen if the first digit of the number was anything other than "0". Otherwise...

```
<.
```

Move c on top of the "1" at the end of the program and print it.

```
 +iB
```

b is still pointing at 19, so we add 19 to the instruction pointer, jumping to the "1" at the end of the program, causing the program to halt after one more cycle. (The extra space is ignored, but we need it there to position this instruction so that the instruction pointer jumps beyond the "]" at the end of the program. If we don't do this, we will enter the loop at the end, and print an extraneous semicolon whenever 0 is input.)

```
-b1
```

This is position 22, so we jump here whenever the number didn't start with "0". We move b back to point at the "0".

```
+CB
```

Add the 48 back to the first digit of the number, restoring it to its proper character value.

```
-CA
```

Subtract the newline from the digit.

```
[+CA.
```

If it's not zero, restore it to its original value and print it.

```
,-CA]
```

Repeat reading digits, comparing them with newline, and printing them until newline is seen.

```
1
```

Data. Ignored. Program halts.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 19 Bytes

```
(x)=>{return x?x:1}
```

Ungolefed, with example:

```
function f(n) {
  if(n)
    return n;
  else
    return 1;
}

f(0); // 1
f(1); // 1
f(2); // 2
```

Comment: [I swear there's a golfier duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118465/48934)

Comment: Whoops :3 I'll search :D

Answer (score 0):

## Swift, 25 bytes

```
max(1, Int(readLine()!)!)
```

If you just have the body of a closure, then it is just 10 bytes:

```
max(1, $0)
```

Takes in standard input and then returns the max int, which would either be 1 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 4 bytes

```
Ｉ∨Ｎ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/charcoal#@/9@z8pHHSve71l3aOf//wYA)

### Explanation

```
Ｉ    Cast (number is casted to string)
 ∨Ｎ¹ input number logical-or 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, 9 bytes

```
f={it?:1}
```

Inside a groovy script file you can run with "groovy -D n=0 ":

```
println System.properties.n?:1
```

As a closure:

```
f={it?:1}
```

1) "?:" is groovy's "[elvis-operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_elvis_operator)"

> One instance of where this is handy is for returning a 'sensible default' value if an expression resolves to false-ish

2) "it" refers to a single anonymous parameter the closure is called with

3) 0 evaluates to false in [groovy-truth](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_numbers_2)

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 13 bytes

```
->i{i==0?1:i}
```

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL, 21 bytes

```
SELECT MAX(1,a)FROM t
```

SQL input is allowed [via a pre-existing named table](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5341/70172) (table *t* with INT field *a*).

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, <sub><s>17</s></sub> 13 Bytes

Anonymous VBE Immediate function that takes input as expected type unsigned integer and then outputs to the VBE immediate window

```vb
?[Max(A1,1)]
```

#### Previous Version

```vb
?[If(A1,A1,1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>3</s> 2 bytes

```
|1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/v8bw////BgA)

#### Ungolfed/Explanation

```
    -- implicit input N
|   -- if N is truthy: N
 1  -- else (N==0): 1
```

Thanks @Zgarb for -1 byte!

Comment: Two bytes: `|1`

Answer (score 0):

## [,,,](https://github.com/totallyhuman/commata), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/totallyhuman/commata/wiki/Code-page)

```
1∨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87PzU0sSfz/3/BRx4r///8bAQA)

,,, is on TIO now, so that's cool. Computes `input or 1` (logical OR) and implicitly outputs the result.

Answer (score 0):

### Element, 8 bytes

```
_2:'!"+`
```

[Try it online](http://Tio.run/##S81JzU3NK/n/P97ISl1RSTvh/38jAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 4 bytes

```
&n+#
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/18tT1v5////hgA)**

```
   #  \ print:
  +   \   input + ...
&n    \   not(input)
```

Answer (score 0):

## **Rust, 27 bytes**

```
|x:u64|if x==0{1}else{x};
```

Anonymous function, or lambda, taking input from x.

First time golfing with Rust, and i must say im quite impressed.

Comment: `|x:u64|x.max(1)`

Answer (score 0):

## Befunge, 6 Bytes

```
&:!+.@
```

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/#%23S0pNK81LT/3/305JP0ZJQVnHXlkh/v9/AA)

```
& Gets input as number
  :! Duplicates and inverts
    +.@ Adds the inverted input to the original, prints and ends the program
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Implicit](//git.io/sS), 7 bytes

```
$!{.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MLchJLS5JTM7@/19FsVrv/38DAA) Explanation:

```
$      read input
 !{    if falsy
   .   increment
       implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## J, 6 Bytes

```
(>.1:)
```

Standard solution: Return the max of 1 and the argument.

The parenthesis ensure it's evaluated as a monadic hook:

```
(>.1:) 0
0 >. (1: 0)    NB. Definition of a monadic hook.
0 >. 1         NB. 1: is a constant function, always returns 1.
1              NB. >. returns the max of its two arguments.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), 9 bytes

```
?0=1
?n=n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85JTcz7n5ufUpqTqpCbmJn3397A1pDLPs82739wSWJRiYKtgr2Cwf9/yWk5ienF/3U9ff67VOYl5mYmFwMA)

Answer (score 0):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 14 bytes

```
(q((n)(i n n 1
```

This is a lambda function. In order to be able to call it, you either need to give it a name using `d` or call it directly (which would require explicitly closing the parentheses before specifying the argument). [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DccxEoAwCAXR3lNQfjpzJJwYh5lIItrk9Mi@aj@11fWdgUot8ADGULJUgrMNfUilroeLr9xbJjWCi10nlZ05fg)

The function takes one argument, `n`. If `n` is truthy (all positive integers), return `n`. Otherwise (zero), return `1`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 41 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate][T N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer][T   T   T   _Retrieve][S N
S _Duplicate_input][N
T   S N
_If_0_jump_to_Label_0][T    N
S T _Print_as_integer][N
N
N
_Exit][N
S S N
_Create_Label_0][S S S T    N
_Push_1][T  N
S T Print_as_integer]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

#### Explanation in pseudo-code:

```
Integer i = STDIN as integer
If i == 0:
  Call function Label_0
Print i
Exit program

function Label_0:
  Print 1
  Exit implicitly with error: Exit not defined
```

#### Example runs:

**Input: `0`**

```
Command    Explanation              Stack    Heap     STDIN    STDOUT    STDERR

SSSN       Push 0                   [0]
SNS        Duplicate top (0)        [0,0]
TNTT       Read STDIN as integer    [0]      {0:0}    0
TTT        Retrieve                 [0]      {0:0}
SNS        Duplicate top (0)        [0,0]    {0:0}
NTSN       If 0: Jump to Label_0    [0]      {0:0}
NSSN       Create Label_0           [0]      {0:0}
SSSTN      Push 1                   [0,1]    {0:0}
TNST       Print as integer         [0]      {0:0}             1
                                                                         error
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgQsIObk4QQDEBhKcIAEgAMkpgOSA/P//DQA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).
Stops with error: Exit not defined.

#### Example runs:

**Input: `5`**

```
Command    Explanation              Stack    Heap     STDIN    STDOUT    STDERR

SSSN       Push 0                   [0]
SNS        Duplicate top (0)        [0,0]
TNTT       Read STDIN as integer    [0]      {0:5}    5
TTT        Retrieve                 [5]      {0:5}
SNS        Duplicate top (5)        [5,5]    {0:5}
NTSN       If 0: Jump to Label_0    [5]      {0:5}
TNST       Print as integer         []       {0:5}             5
NNN        Exit program             []       {0:5}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgQsIObk4QQDEBhKcIAEgAMkpgOSA/P//TQE) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

Answer (score 0):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 5 bytes

```
I:z+h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/39OqShtIGQAA)

Given `n`, calculate `n + !n`, print as int and halt. Unfortunately `Gol><>` doesn't have implicit input option, so the bytes are the same as regular `><>`.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
_+
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/Xvv/fwMA) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn2ly/947f86/w24DLmMuEy5DIEMI1MA).

**2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) alternative by *@Adnan*:**

```
$M
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fxff/fwMA) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/m9l/F97/OfwMuQy4jLlMuQyDDyBQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
_   # Check if the (implicit) input is 0 (0 becomes 1; everything else becomes 0)
 +  # Add it to the (implicit) input (0 becomes 1; everything else stays the same)
    # (and output the result implicitly)

$   # Push both 1 and the input to the stack
 M  # Push the largest number of the stack (without changing the rest of the stack)
    # (and output the top of the stack implicitly as result)
```

Comment: @Makonede I'm afraid those don't work.. `$~` and `1~` fail for even-numbered inputs (i.e. `4` results in `5`; `6` results in `7`; etc.) And the `1M` will always result in `1`, because it's the only value on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 2 bytes

```
1Ṁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/3/Dhzob//40B)

Takes the `Ṁ`ax of `1` and the input.

Answer (score 0):

## [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP),  <strike>4</strike>  20 bytes

```
%@_1A[1A~25WWM~]~?1:
```

Responds to numbers which have more than 1 digit.

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/?code=%3Cspan%20style%3D%22font-size%3A%2021.6px%3B%22%3E%25%40_1A%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cspan%20style%3D%22font-size%3A%2021.6px%3B%22%3E%5B1A%7E25WWM%7E%5D%7E%3F1%3A%3C%2Fspan%3E&input=2)

Comment: I tried the Keg solution, and it outputs nothing after 9.

Comment: You were right. The Keg solution has now been fixed.

Comment: @Razetime that's because it was trying to output it as a character. It needed a sneaky `-hr` interpreter flag.

Comment: nice! Happy to help.

Comment: Problem was that the poster (petStorm) had deleted that account long ago. So it needed someone else to fix it.

Comment: Opening issue about inadequate input for multi-digit numbers in MAWP

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, <s>*8*</s> 11 bytes

Probably a bad implementation, but here:

```javascript
n=>n==0?1:n
```

Explanation:

```javascript
n // The input
n == 0 // Checks whether n is zero
?1 // If so, return 1.
:n // However, if n isn't zero, then return n
```

Comment: Welcome to CGCC. Your approach works, but note that either a full program or function is required; hard-coded input is [not](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2423/92901) [allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8731/92901). Something like [this](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i7P1tbA3tAq739yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahoGmJheqiCGGiBGGiLGm5n8A "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online") would be acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've solved the problems, and rectified the things that need fixing!

Comment: you can change `n==0` to `n<1` since input is non-negative for -1 byte

Comment: `n||1` works fine

Answer (score 0):

## MMIX, 8 bytes (2 instrs)

(jxd)

```
00000000: 6300 0001 f801 0000                      c¡¡¢ẏ¢¡¡
```

(assembly)

```
foo CSZ $0,$0,1
    POP 1,0
```

Honestly, this function really should be inlined. It costs three instructions to call, but just one to inline.

Answer (score 0):

## Swift, 12 bytes

### Types provided, 12 bytes

```swift
{$0==0?1:$0}
```

```swift
{
  $0 == 0 ? 1 : $0
}
```

### Types not provided, 20 bytes

````swift
{(n:Int)in n==0?1:n}

```swift
{ (number: Int) -> Int in
  number == 0 ? 1 : number
}
````

Comment: [orangebutton](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/116131/orangebutton) suggests [the following golf to 11 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/66806)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>63</s> 42 bytes

```c
main(i){scanf("%i",&i);printf("%i",i?:1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS/@vnJmXnFOakqpgU1ySkpmvl2H3PzcxM08jU7O6ODkxL01DSTVTSUctU9O6oCgzrwTKz7S3MtS0rv3/3wAA)

Much readable than C answers that already exists here. An if-else statement whether to output 1 or the other.

Thanks to ceilingcat for golfing 21 bytes.

Comment: If statement is an overkill for such task......

Comment: @Wasif It's pretty much the way for beginners. Using if statements always help with programs, and so here it is. Except ceilingcat has golfed it that it's not very visible.

Comment: brevity/creativity is the target of code golf, readability be dammed, an if statement is sooooo boring, after the golf it looks much better, you might want to check [Tips for golfing in C](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2203/tips-for-golfing-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 2 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 1.65 bytes

```
1~
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhaLDOsgDCh_wUIDCAMA)

Explanation: logical OR (`~`) with `1`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 3 bytes

```
1←↑
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f/f8FHbhEdtE///NwEA)

```
1       push 1
 ←      get input
  ↑     get maximum value on the stack; implicit print
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 15 Bytes

```python
lambda x:x or 1
```

Thanks for choosing a falsey value to avoid!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqkIhv0jB8H9BUWZeiUaaBojMzCsoLdHQBIL/BgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Desmoslang](https://github.com/theRealDadsdy/Desmos-Userscript/tree/main/Desmos%20Programming%20Language), <strike>14</strike> 13 Bytes

```
IS+1-\sgn(DOT
```

Old:

```
ISE\{D=0,D\}OT
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 24 bytes

```lua
print(0<0+...and...or 1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0TDwMZAW09PLzEvBUjmFykYav7//98AAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 21 bytes

```python
lambda n:{n:n,0:1}[n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PycxNyklUSHPqjrPKk/HwMqwNjov9v9/AA)

Also note that `{0:1,n:n}` doesn't work because if n is 0 the `n:n` overrides `0:1`

Answer (score 0):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 5 characters

```
\A0=1
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.2$ gema '\A0=1' <<< '0'
1

bash-5.2$ gema '\A0=1' <<< '10'
10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/P8bRwNbw/38DAA) / [Try all test cases online!](https://tio.run/##lc89T8MwEAbgOf4VVyvU7RDlo18DskQHBiYk1jRCaXKlFSWJYldCKvz2cGeLlgEGlvMj@c5@b1ua/VBjdSx7hGgNFo19rkqDeiKCXCWq0Ckj/UZGyBgzwowxJ8wZC8KCsSQsGSvCyo27hxJP70RMhej6Q2N3oD7gJkoTA7@cGdVNo0A9NN3J0vmE5nRk3L93WFmsiY@vSohd28OBm6iCDM@jyzL5XfEpb6FuRdC7aS3DCWC1byHiVjcl6be47Wz8gm9lbPrKAdSwWSc6HRRMpRDBPxJf3pWh/5V1voby15QMOE2e/@jT@q/WooDx2EfnrTlU3TY4fAE)

Answer (score 0):

## Swift, <s>19</s> <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```swift
var f={max(1,$0)}
```

Taking advantage of the "non-negative" rule here.

Answer (score 0):

## [Easyfuck](https://github.com/Quadruplay/easyfuck/wiki), 5 bytes

Solution:

```
+$":'
```

Explanation:

```
+ increments the cell at the pointer
$ copies cell at the pointer into storage
" takes in an 8 bit integer
: puts max(current cell, storage) into the current cell
' outputs an 8 bit integer
```

Answer (score -1):

### Excel VBA 17 bytes

```
[a1]=IIF(n=0,1,n)
```

Simple if else statement you can run it from vba immediate window

Comment: Hey, just a note on convention with VBA and Excel VBA for PPCG - you _must_ take input from either a cell or from a passed variable. You can output to the immediate window, msgbox, function value, to a cell or by modifying a passed variable. This means that your above solution is not valid as it does not take input from cell or a passed variable, but rather relies on the variable being passed to it.

Comment: Save two bytes *and* make it a valid answer with `?-([A1]=0)+[A1]`

Answer (score -1):

## JS ES5, 26 bytes

```js
function (n){return n?n:1}
```

Comment: Save one byte by removing the space after `function`.

Comment: ``````n||1``````

Comment: I think you can also write this as `function(n)n||1` (taking the `n||1` idea from l4m2)