# Create an ASCII line, given a length

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

### Information

Create a diagonal line given its length (let’s call the variable, say, \$n\$ where \$n > 0\$)

- The diagonal line starts from the top left and goes to the bottom right.
- You **must** use the ASCII character `\` for the line.
- The input number can be given from STDIN or if your program doesn’t support that, use a hardcoded value in your code or pass it as an argument while running the program.
- For padding, **only use** the **space character** `0x20`
- *Trailing spaces* and/or *newlines* are **allowed**.
- The **length** of the line is the **non whitespace** characters

Here is an example program (59 bytes):

```py
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
  print(' ' * i + '\\')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P0/BViEzr0QjM6@gtERDU5MrLb9IIRMopFCUmJeeqpGnacWloFBQBFKjrqCuoAWU1FZQj4lR1/z/3wQA)

Example:

```
Input: 4
Output
\
 \
  \
   \
```

#### Rules

- Use *standard* I/O when possible.
- Standard *loopholes* are forbidden.
- This is code golf, so the shortest answer in bytes wins.
- Please explain the code that you wrote.

Comment: This was on [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/22410#22410) for a couple of days :)

Comment: Does the explanation count towards the byte count :?

Comment: The explanation is only for how the program works

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/125117/66833)

Comment: This is quite possibly the fastest-answered question of all time: 1 hour, 18 answers.

Comment: I suggest removing the rule "Use Standard I/O when possible". We have well-accepted [default rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) for I/O, and it would be unfair to _force_ the use of standard I/O just because it is _possible_ for a given language

Comment: I'd suggest not accepting an answer (or at least not accepting one so quickly) in the future, as it may discourage others from answering.

Comment: @ophact, I'd be surprised if it even comes close; it's par for the course (every pun intended!) with trivial challenges.

Comment: [10 bytes in Perl](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoiMDAwMDAwMDA6IDczNjEgNzkyNyA1YzBjIDI3NzggM2MzZSAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgc2F5J1xcLid4PD4iLCJhcmdzIjoiLU01LjEwLjAiLCJpbnB1dCI6IjQifQ==) but uses ANSI escape codes, not spaces :(

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 1 [byte](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

Better tool for the job ;)

```
＼
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjND,i=NA__,v=8)

Given an integer, this draws a diagonal of that string. If you pass a string instead, this prints the string along the diagonal. There is matching anti-diagonal builtin `／` as well.

Comment: lol, wow. definitely the perfect tool to pick :p

Comment: 13 hours too late for this :p

Comment: @Razetime 5 minutes too late to comment this...

Answer (score 10):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 2 bytes

```
↖Ｎ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R27T3e9b9/28CAA)

right tool for the job

Comment: [Also 2 bytes](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R24z3e9b9/28CAA)

Answer (score 7):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 9 bytes ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Returns a list of string, as per [meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17095/43319).

```apl
'\'↑⍨¨-∘⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///Xz1G/VHbxEe9Kw6t0H3UMeNR7@b/aY/aJjzq7XvU1fyod82j3i2H1huDlPRNDQ5yBpIhHp7B/4G0V7C/n0KaggkA)

`∘⍳` indices one through \$n\$, then:

`-` negate those

`¨` for each:

`↑⍨` take (when negative: from the rear) that many characters (padding with spaces) from:

`'\'` the backslash character

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
=þị⁾\ Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/28L6Hu7sfNe6LUYj8//@/CQA)

```
Ḷ⁶ẋp”\Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjm2PGrc93NVd8Khhbkzk////TQA)

### How they work

```
=þị⁾\ Y - Main link. Takes N on the left
=þ      - Yield the identity matrix of size N
  ị⁾\   - Index into "\ ", replacing 1 with "\" and 0 with " "
      Y - Join by newlines
```

```
Ḷ⁶ẋp”\Y - Main link. Takes N on the left
Ḷ       - Range [0, ..., N-1]
 ⁶ẋ     - Repeat that many spaces for each
   p”\  - Append "\" to each
      Y - Join by newlines
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
õ!ù'\
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=9SH5J1w&input=OA)

```
õ!ù'\     :Implicit input of integer
õ         :Range [1,input]
 !ù'\     :For each, left pad "\" to that length with spaces
          :Implicit output joined with newlines
```

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-mR`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
'\iUç
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW1S&code=J1xpVec&input=OA)

```
'\iUç     :Implicit map of each U in the range [0,input)
'\i       :Prepend to "\"
   Uç     :  Space repeated U times
          :Implicit output joined with newlines
```

Answer (score 6):

## [51AC8](https://github.com/PyGamer0/51AC8), 10 bytes

```
R[\ ×\\+t]
```

[Try it Online!](https://pygamer0.pythonanywhere.com/?flags=&header=&code=R%5B%5C%20%C3%97%5C%5C%2Bt%5D&footer=&stdin=4)

*-2 bytes* due to an update.

*-7 bytes* due to an update introducing for_each loops and range.

*-1 byte* online interpreter and implicit input.

### Explanation

```
       # Implicit Input (STDIN) and push to stack
R      # Range from 0 to input (exclusive)
[      # Start for each
  \    # Push ' ' to the stack
  ×    # Multiply the top 2 elements on the stack
  \\   # Push '\'
  +    # Add top 2 elements
  t    # Pop and print top of stack
]      # End of while loop
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 37 bytes

```python
x='\\'
exec'print x;x=" "+x;'*input()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8JWPSZGnSu1IjVZvaAoM69EocK6wlZJQUm7wlpdKzOvoLREQ/P/fxMA)

Answer (score 5):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 37 bytes

```c
f(n){printf("%*c\n",n--,92,n&&f(n));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///P00jT7O6oCgzryRNQ0lVKzkmT0knT1dXx9JIJ09NDSSraV37PzcxM09DU6GaS0EhTcNQ0xpMG0FpYyhtAqRr/wMA)

---

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 39 bytes

A recursive version suggested by [@att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/att).

```c
f(n){--n&&f(n);printf("%*c\n",n+1,92);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zWlc3T00NxLIuKMrMK0nTUFLVSo7JU9LJ0zbUsTTStK79n5uYmaehqVDNpaCQpmGoaQ2mjaC0MZQ2AdK1/wE)

---

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 44 bytes

```c
i;f(n){for(i=0;i++<n;)printf("%*c\n",i,92);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOk0jT7M6Lb9II9PWwDpTW9smz1qzoCgzryRNQ0lVKzkmT0knU8fSSNO69n9uYmaehqZCNZeCQpqGoaY1mDaC0sZQ2gRI1/4HAA)

Comment: [39 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zWlc3T00NxLIuKMrMK0nTUFLVSo7JU9LJ0zbUsTTStK79n5uYmaehqVDNpaCQpmGoaQ2mjaC0MZQ2AdK1/wE)

Comment: @att Nice. That leads to a 37-byte version with clang. Undefined behavior for the win! ;-)

Answer (score 5):

## Dyalog APL, <s>16</s> 14 bytes

Solution - Takes in number of lines as input from user, and returns a
string of diagonal line.

`' \'[1+∘.=⍨⍳⎕]`

#### Explanation

```
⎕            ⍝ ⎕ takes input from the user (number of lines)
             ⍝ In the below explanation, I have assumed ⎕ = 9 as input
⍳⎕            ⍝ 1 to 9 : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
∘.=          ⍝ Outer Product with Equality
⍨            ⍝ Apply a function with same argument on both sides
∘.=⍨⍳⎕       ⍝ ∘.=⍨ function applied to array ⍳⎕ = [1,2..9]
             ⍝ This is same as (⍳9) ∘.= (⍳9), which produces Identity Matrix of size 9
1+∘.=⍨⍳⎕     ⍝ Add 1 to each element of previous matrix (since APL uses 1-based index)
' \'[1+∘.=⍨⍳⎕] ⍝ From the string ' \', select characters specified by indices in 1+∘.=⍨⍳⎕
```

Comment: `⎕` actually reads from the input section on TIO, but the [way the program is run](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/blob/master/wrappers/apl-dyalog) it doesn't implicitly output, you would need to prepend `⎕←` to get output. The way to "enable" implicit output is to wrap the program into a tradfn and call that: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97b@6Qox6tKH2o44ZeraPelc86t38qG9qLEjufxqXMQA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Comment: @ovs How exactly is a tradfn different from a normal function definition? And how do you "enable" implicit I/O in tryapl.org (or, if this is not possible from the site, from Dyalog APL Windows Editor) ?

Comment: Oh sorry I misread your post, tryapl.org indeed does not support `⎕`. If you want to add a link for others to try this online, you could use the TIO one I sent above. I don't have Windows but I would assume that you can run `' \'[1+∘.=⍨⍳⎕]` and then enter the number ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVHx4.gif)). And *tradfn* is short for [*traditional function*](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Defined_function_(traditional))

Answer (score 5):

## brainfuck, 113 bytes

```
,>>+++++++[<+++++++++++++>-]<+>++++++++++>>++++[<++++++++>-]<<<<[>>>>[->+>+<<]>[-<+>]>[<<<.>>>-]<<<<<.>.>>+<<<<-]
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fx85OGwKibbSRgZ1urI22HRLfDlURSB4Iou2AIFrXDqjUxiYWyAJqAlJAGT2gBEQNkAnkaINYurH//ysCAA)

First time poster. This was a fun exercise! Please provide criticism, I pretty much went in cold when writing this.

```
, how long the line should be via char code
>

initialize cell 1 with "\"
>+++++++[<+++++++++++++>-]<+
> 

initialize cell 2 with "\n"
++++++++++
>

initialize cell 3 with " "; go back to beginning
>++++[<+++++>-]<
<<<

start loop at cell 0
[
    >>>> go to cell 4
    [
        ->+>+<< copy the pad value to cells 5 and 6
    ]
    
    > now we move cell 5 to cell 4
    [
        -<+> cell 4 keeps track how much padding we'll need for our next iteration
    ]
    >

    cell 6 keeps track of how many spaces we need to print currently
    [
        <<<  go to space char
        .    print it
        >>>- decrease counter
    ]

    <<<<< move to line char
    .>.   print line and newline
    >>+   move to cell 4 and increase our padding by 1
    <<<<- back to cell 0; subtract line counter
]
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
Ṭ€ị⁾\ Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzjWPmtY83N39qHFfjELk////TQA)

<s>Working on golfing. This is longer than I remember it being possible.</s> The JHT exercise allows other characters so I can't get this to 5 bytes because of that :/

```
Ṭ€ị⁾\ Y    Main Link
 €         For each (implicit range)
Ṭ          Generate a boolean list with 1s at the indices
  ị        Index that into
   ⁾\      "\ "
      Y    and join on newlines
```

Comment: How did you create the answer so fast?? I think you guys have some sort of unicode keyboard to enter theses characters very quickly    :P

Comment: @MaanasB I have the wiki pages bookmarked and then I just copy-paste, lol. This is a standard exercise from the Jelly Hyper-Training room and it's a pretty simple challenge (not that that's bad, of course!)

Comment: @MaanasB, I have (almost) all of the characters Japt uses on my phone's keyboard.

Comment: :/ two byte character literals. I'm disappointed in you, jelly :P

Comment: @Wzl ? (filler filler)

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 10 bytes

```
' \'{~=@i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/1RVi1KvrbB0y9f5rcqUmZ@QraFinaSoYIbFNkNhm/wE)

Answer (score 4):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>90</s> <s>77</s> 60 bytes

```c
i;main(n){for(scanf("%i",&n);i<n;printf("%*s\\\n",i++,""));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchLCoAgFAXQrcSLQsuaNVJaiROx34O6RtooWrvRGR7f@d1hzSXD7/c0FyamiUO/jZn14RgC8lnCJaJ3WARVTKqG1Gygz4uR/muitRakuG0VkZT6zXn4AA)

My first work without `int` in it while still using it. I'm doing better now, aren't I?

Thanks to att for golfing 13 bytes. Thanks to ceilingcat for golfing 17 bytes.

Comment: [-13](https://tio.run/##FcpLDoMgEADQq5hpNEygppuuBj2JG4K/IXYkgqumZ0f71s8//eZkKQ8Wv53jVNmUR97btS9sghH6OBaF33k/VPJOZgU1g2kEibW2QvHMScEwAOL/hO5FWgfLhPFgyfevAOlXyvsC) using `for` instead of `while`

Comment: [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS/@vnJmXnFOakqpgU1ySkpmvl2H3P9M6NzEzTyNPszotv0ijODkxL01DSTVTSUctT9M60ybPuqAoM68EJKaVHJOnpKOtnaljaaSpaV37/78pAA "C (clang) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [convey](http://xn--wxa.land/convey/), 46 bytes

```
[0>>,+1
   v"^
{,"=@#]}
 >^}"~v#'\\'
' '!""~/}
```

[Try it online!](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoiWzA+PiwrMVxuICAgdlwiXlxueyxcIj1AI119XG4gPl59XCJ+diMnXFxcXCdcbicgJyFcIlwifi99IiwidiI6MSwiaSI6IjIwIn0=)

Visualization (i use '_' instead of space because the gif doesnt show the space char if i use it, but in the official page the output works whit spaces):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `M`, 7 bytes

```
(nI\\+,
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJNIiwiIiwiKG5JXFxcXCssIiwiIiwiNSJd)

Explanation:

```
(  # range from 0 to implict input
  n  # loop variable
   I  # push that many spaces
    \\  # backslash literal
      +  # concatenate the spaces with the backslash
       ,  # print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
'\3Λ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fPcb43Oz//00A)

Using the input as length, draw `\` in direction `3` (down-right) with the canvas builtin `Λ`. See [Kevin's tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175520/64121) for details on how the canvas works

---

6 bytes without the canvas builtin:

```
'\ILj»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fPcbTJ@vQ7v//TQA)

For each number in the range `IL == [1..input]`, pad the string `"\"` with leading spaces to this length (`j`). `»` joins the results by newlines.

Another 6 bytes solution suggested by [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen):

```
L<'\ú»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fx0Y95vCuQ7v//zcBAA)

For each number in the range `L< == [0..input-1]`, pad the string `"\"` with that many leading spaces.

Comment: n o o o friggin ninjas

Comment: Alternative 6-byter using `ú`: `Ý¨'\ú»`/`L<'\ú»`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks, added the second suggestion. It would be really nice if `j` would automatically swap arguments for integer lists as well.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 33 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,s=`\\
`)=>--n?s+f(n,' '+s):s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjT6fYNiEmhitB09ZOVzfPvlg7DSimrqCuXaxpVfw/OT@vOD8nVS8nP10jTcNQU5MLVcQIQ8QYQ8REU/M/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## MATLAB/Octave, <s>32</s> 31 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo)*

```matlab
disp([60*eye(input(''))+32,''])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z@SWVygoe6ZV1BaYmWorgnhR5sZaKVWpmpkgoQ11NU1NbWNjXTU1WM1UdSbqGtygfnJGYlFGtj0aEIVQDWYk6rB0IwIHf8NuUy4zLkMzQA)
Reads the length from standard input, writes to standard output.
Makes use of identity matrix `eye(x)`.

---

Alternatively, using function input/output, **<s>22</s> 21 bytes**:

```matlab
@(x)[60*eye(x)+32,'']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQaNCM9rMQCu1MhXI0jY20lFXj/2fZpuYV2zNlZJZXKCh7plXUFpiZaiuCeGnaRhqaqJIGSOkjNGkTBBSJmhS5ggpczQpQyMky4zQJI0MEJJGBpqa/wE)
Anonymous function, outputs character array.

Answer (score 3):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
■♦9
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=fe0439&i=5)

### Explanation

```
m'\)
m    map 1..n and print with newlines
 '\) pad \ on the left with spaces to given length
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 46 bytes

```python
for i in range(int(input())):print(' '*i+'\\')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1VIzOvBIgLSks0NDU1rQqKQHx1BXWtTG31mBh1zf//TQA)

Comment: you should not answer your own question so soon

Comment: welp sorry didnt know that

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>42</s>, 39 bytes

- -3 bytes thanks to @Dominic van Essen

```r
write(strrep("\\",diag(x<-scan())),1,x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7wosyRVo7ikqCi1QEMpJkZJJyUzMV2jwka3ODkxT0NTU1PHUKdC87/5fwA)

**Explanation:**

- take x from standard input,
- create a diagonal matrix of size x
- repeat the character `'\'` one time for each 1 of the matrix and 0-times for each 0 (= empty string)
- print the matrix separating each character with a space

Comment: [39 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7wosyRVo7ikqCi1QEMpJkZJJyUzMV2jwka3ODkxT0NTU1PHUKdC87/5fwA) using ```strrep```...  but I've found [another approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/228997/95126) that's still shorter (so far)...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Thanks! updated

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `jṀ`, 4 bytes

```
ƛ\\꘍
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j%E1%B9%80&code=%C6%9B%5C%5C%EA%98%8D&inputs=4&header=&footer=)

Flags go brrr

```
ƛ\\꘍   Full Program
ƛ      For each (implicity loops from 0 to n - 1)
 \\    push '\'
   ꘍   prepend x spaces to '\'
```

`Ṁ` is equivalent to `mM`, which makes implicit range start at `0` instead of `1` and end at `n - 1` instead of `n`.

`j` joins the top of the stack on newlines at the end.

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 30 bytes

```
repeat i n[print pad/left"\"i]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmqIQHauQZ6VgaPC/KLUgNbFEIVMhL7qgKDOvRKEgMUU/JzWtRClGKTP2/38A)

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 56 bytes

```java
n->{for(var s="\\";n-->0;s=" "+s)System.out.println(s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU6xDoIwFJzhKxomGkPj4FZlcXJwYhSHWgopwivpeyUxhG@vjfGWy90ldzeqVVVj945LeE1WMz0pRHZXFtiWs4S/j6Qo0epsx@aUlg15C8PjyZQfkG95NqYmEchOog@gyToQVwcYZuPPNyAzGF/3lwhVvfXOl6vyDC9F2xYSqqo@yiRYcUDefJDMLFwgsaQJmqBELvco86wXSmuzUHni8nduz/f4BQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 10 bytes

```
ri{S*'\N}%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vyizOlhLPcavVvX/f1MA)

#### Explanation

```
r             e# Read input
 i            e# Evaluate as an integer, n
  {     }%    e# Do the following for each k in [0 1 ... n-1]
              e# Push k (implicit)
   S          e# Push space
    *         e# Repeat. Gives a string with k spaces
     '\       e# Push character "\"
       N      e# Push newline
              e# Output the stack (implicit)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 35 bytes

```r
cat(sep="\\
",strrep(" ",0:scan()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKM4tcBWKSaGS0mnuKSoKLVAQ0lBScfAqjg5MU9DU1Pzv/l/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://www.php.net/), <strike>58</strike> 57 bytes

```
for($i=0;$i<$argv[1];$i++)echo str_repeat(' ',$i)."\\\n";
```

[Try it here!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNFQybQ2sVTJtVBKL0suiDWOBbG1tzdTkjHyF4pKi@KLUgtTEEg11BXUdlUxNPaWYmJg8Jev///@bAAA)

This is my first golf, so feel free to mention anything I can do to improve this!

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in PHP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2913/tips-for-golfing-in-php) page for ways you can golf your program. Note that assuming the input is saved in a variable (e.g. `$n`) is not an [acceptable method of input](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). Instead, you should take input via command line arguments, as a function argument or via STDIN

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Thanks! I'll update it with a new version that takes input

Comment: I'm not a PHP expert, but I can help improve your answer to [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxVMm1UEovSy6INY601U5Mz8hWKS4rii1ILUhNLNNQV1HVUMrW1NfWUYriUrP///28CAA).

Comment: ...and down to 35 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxVEovSy6INY3V1rVUq9GzVFdQ1U5Mz8pVUKmK4lKz///9vAgA "PHP – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 40 bytes

```
[ iota [ [ bl ] times "\\"print ] each ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqVQnFpYmpqXnFqskJmvkJtYkqGQnVqUl5qjYM3FZfI/GihakqgQDYRJOQqxCiWZuUCVSjExSgVFmXklQJHUxOQMhdj/yYk5Of8B)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 34 bytes

```perl
s//\\/;$==<>;s// / while(say,$=--)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X1qcqlBmqmdoYP2/WF8/JkbfWsXW1sbOGshR0Fcoz8jMSdUoTqzUUbHV1dX8/98UAA)

This should be run from the command line like `perl -E 's//\\/;$==<>;s// / while(say,$=--)'` to activate the `say` feature without adding any bytes.

Ungolfed:

```perl
$_='\\'; #Set the default variable $_ to a single backslash
$==<>; #Take input into $=. This variable converts the input to an integer
while($=--){ #Decrement $= and loop
    say; #Prints $_ and a newline
    $_=" $_"; #Adds a space to the start of $_
}
```

Uses `s// /` as shorthand for `$_=" $_"` (i.e. to prepend a space to `$_`). Putting `say` into the while loop lets us drop the brackets from the loop body.

Comment: 24 bytes with the same idea: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X1qcqlBmqmdoYP2/OLFSp1hfX0FfIS2/SEMl3rbM0kizwsbu/39TAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: @Sisyphus Wow, that's impressive. I had no idea you use `x` like that. Feel free to post that as your own answer- it's plenty different from mine. ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/), 41 bytes

```
puts Array.new(gets.to_i){|i|(' '*i+'\\')}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6C0pFjBsagosVIvL7VcIz21pFivJD8@U7O6JrNGQ11BXStTWz0mRl2z9v9/QyMA)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer.

Comment: you can get [33](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/Pz21pFivJD8@U68kMze1uLoms6agtKRYXUFdK1PbPiam9v9/QyMA "Ruby – Try It Online") with a full program, and [30](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X9euorpCryQzN7W4uiazpqC0pFhdQV0rU9s@Jqa29v9/QyMA "Ruby – Try It Online") with a lambda.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome @redwolf-programs!  Nice one @Razetime, 33!

Answer (score 2):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 34 bytes

```
{for(;$1--;x=x" ")y=y x"\\\n"}$0=y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SMNaxVBX17rCtkJJQUmz0rZSoUIpJiYmT6lWxcC28v9/CwA)

This is pretty straightforward I suppose...  Each time through the loop creates a string corresponding to one line of output.  The control just counts decrements the first commandline argument until it's 0.

```
 for(;$1--;      )
```

The body of the loop appends the current output line to an accumulator variables, taking the current "padding" of blanks and appending `\` and '\n` to it.

```
                  y=y x"\\\n"
```

The "end of loop" expression builds up the padding variable.

```
           x=x" "
```

Then once all the lines have been generated, assigning that output string to `$0` as a truthy test, without an action, causes the output to be printed.

```
                               $0=y
```

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 24 bytes

```
0(10)'\<n[>&:[o]p' <1-]<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/99Aw9BAUz3GJi/aTs0qOj@2QF3BxlA31ub/f1MA)

This is really a translation of the approach, just in Ly. So I'm not adding a separate entry for it.

The first task is to push a null terminated string `\\n` onto the stack.

```
0(10)'\
```

Then shift to a new stack and read in the number of lines.

```
       <n
```

The construct to loop that many times shifts between stacks a decrements the top of the stack with the loop counter until it hits 0.

```
         [>        <1-]
```

The body of the loop, duplicates the stack with the output string on top of itself `&:` then prints up to the first `\0`, deletes that null and adds a space.  So each iteration prints the current line and appends a space to the front in anticipation of the next iteration.

```
           &:[o]p'
```

When the loop ends and all the lines have been printed, we just need to switch stacks to avoid printing what's left.

```
                       <
```

Answer (score 2):

## **[BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/)**, 12 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
↕⌽⁼⎉0‿1↑⟜"\"
```

[Try it here.](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oaV4oy94oG84o6JMOKAvzHihpHin5wiXCIKCkYgNA==)

```
↕⌽⁼⎉0‿1↑⟜"\" # tacit function which takes an int and returns a character array
       ↑⟜"\" # take input number of characters from the string "\", padding with spaces
 ⌽⁼          # rotate-inverse (right instead of left),
   ⎉0‿1      #   rank 0‿1 (each scalar on the left pairs with a vector on the right)
↕            # by the indices 0 ... input
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Lolwho.Cares](https://valthe.scheffers.net/testing/lolwhocares), 183 bytes

```
* >2,*1210+10 0*+ 0>,02001*101v
                   ^ 010121   <
  ^           121021<
    >*+102021**+vv             <
v 120210021`1012<   +**120021 <
>*101*10102 2012 >*1012+201020`^
```

Given a decimal number N, will output a line of length N.

Explanation:

```
* >2,*1210+10 0*+ 0>,02001*101v
                   ^ 010121   <
  ^           121021<
```

This code reads from the input, and converts ascii decimal to a number.
Side effect of it's working means it pushes N, followed by 0.

It does so by first reading a character, finishing when it read 0 (EOF).
It then multiplies the current number by 10, and finally it subtracts 48 from the ASCII value and adds.

```
    >*+102021**+vv             <
v 120210021`1012<   +**120021 <
>*101*10102 2012 >*1012+201020`^
```

This code takes [N, 0] pushed by the other function and draws a line accordingly.
This makes use of the fact that the stack is "initialised" with an infinite amount of 0s at the bottom.

This is basically an implementation of nested for loops;
It checks whether enough lines have been printed, then prints X spaces, followed by \ and newline.

The language is a custom esoteric programming language, similar to BEFUNGE (as [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792/user) pointed out [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/118444/stay-away-from-zero/229011?noredirect=1#comment526275_229011)).

Note: Due to the implementation of number reading, care must be taken to omit any non-decimal characters, including leading/trailing spacing/newlines.

[Online interpreter](https://valthe.scheffers.net/testing/lolwhocares)

Comment: now i just need to see one in asciidots

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 22 bytes

```
{[~] (' 'Xx^$_)X~'\
'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OrouVkFDXUE9oiJOJV4zok49hku99n9xYqVCmoahgab1fwA)

`' ' Xx ^$_` generates a list of the spaces starting each line.  `X~ '\␤'` appends a backslash and newline to each of those strings, then `[~]` concatenates them.

Answer (score 2):

## [Regenerate](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Regenerate) `-l`, 4 bytes

```
 *\\
```

Takes input as the argument to the `-l` flag; for example,

```
python3 regenerate.py -r ' *\\' -l 4
\
 \
  \
   \
```

[Try it here!](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/regenerate)

#### Explanation

The regex  `*\\` matches 0 or more spaces, followed by a backslash. Regenerate finds all strings that match that regex, starting from the shortest: `\`,  `\`,   `\`, and so forth. By default, each match is printed on its own line, and the `-l N` option limits the output to the first N matches.

Answer (score 2):

## [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 39 bytes

We save some bytes by using an infix `Array` over `Range`, `Table` over `StringRepeat`, and `Echo` over `Print`.

We also cut it down to 33 bytes in TIO, because user input for Mathematica wasn't working :)

```
Echo[Table[" ",#]<>"\\"]&~Array~Input[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/981OSM/OiQxKSc1WklBSUc51sZOKSZGKVatzrGoKLGyzvT/fwA)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), <s>14</s> 11 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
" \\"⊏˜↕=⌜↕
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RuKGkCIgXFwi4oqPy5zihpU94oyc4oaVCkYgNA==)

*¯3 thanks to @ovs*

Comment: `" \\"⊏˜↕=⌜↕` works as a tacit function: https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RuKGkCIgXFwi4oqPy5zihpU94oyc4oaVCkYgNA==

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 42 bytes

```lua
for i=1,...do print((" "):rep(i).."\\")end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/Lb9IIdPWUEdPTy8lX6GgKDOvRENDSUFJ06ootUAjU1NPTykmRkkzNS/l////JgA)

Answer (score 2):

## Kotlin, 56 Bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcuxCoNADADQXwm3mOCiq1aho3NXl4BWDjVKmgpy3Lef4v7evNniJaXvX2BArjoxCgcrWONcreM@siFT2NWLLYKWZ32fUW1548DF@MSVvSDr9Kvgrcrn62M3n1qCMGBZUEwX)

```kotlin
fun d(a:Int){var t="";repeat(a){println(t+'\\');t+=" "}}
```

ungolfed version
I think this code is obvious enough

```kotlin
fun d(a:Int)
{
    var t = ""
    repeat(a)
    {
        println(t + '\\')
        t += " "
    }
}
```

Comment: the `\\`s are spaced apart :/

Comment: And you can use the header and footer on TIO like this: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@/8/rTRPIUUj0cozr0SzuiyxSKHEVknJuii1IDWxRCNRs7qgKDOvJCdPo0RbPSZGXdO6RNtWSUFBqbYWrDM3MTNPQ7M6RcPQQLP2PwA "Kotlin – Try It Online")

Comment: @PyGamer0 wait, the spaces are meant to incerment by 1 and not 2? well i can fix that, tomorrow. thx btw

Comment: It's been more than a month but I finally fixed it.
@PyGamer0 Also thanks for tip

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-n -M5.10.0`, 24 bytes

```perl
say$"x$_,v92 for 0..--$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJFqUIlXqfM0kghLb9IwUBPT1dXJf7/f9N/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DA30DP7r5gEA)

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 8 bytes

```
" \\"@=:
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxNj8+KAjEMxu95ijJ40EMt+Ad2WwQvHjz5AFawdDMzxdqO04yMyO6z2+LBDeQjv/AlJLWsmNbVdiMBSD4nx8dfL2vG2KjO8aKm59o4r0b1UP3s9Js9x5WaVlpnRwWsRJn/B4U+UHbPTgACoCXqkhTCxh9soq/niYy94GhbExqc23gVtwETuRiSWCy+vtdLYXs0hNwEbpJ1jnsXkDfujrnBPYaGWoDdaK6dx/zAPnQDSbaCw0C5AqbzISXfkvUFZtdCvw==)

- `=:` generate an `n` by `n` identity matrix
- `" \\"@` index into a string containing two characters - a space, and a backslash

Answer (score 2):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), <s>5</s> 4 bytes (8 nibbles)

*-2 nibbles thanks to a [hint](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63580242#63580242) from [Darren Smith](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/94929/darren-smith)*

```
$&" "$"\\"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboW61S41BSUgFBFQSkmRgkiCJVbsNAEwgAA)

#### Explanation

```
$&" "$"\\"
$           Input number
            (Implicit) Map over range from 1 to that number:
 &            Left-justify
      "\\"    string containing a backslash
     $        to a width given by the function argument
  " "         by padding with spaces
            Output each element of that list on a separate line (implicit)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 6 bytes

```
ʁð*\\+
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%CA%81%C3%B0*%5C%5C%2B&inputs=4&header=&footer=)

```
ʁð*\\+    
ʁ         Push range(input)
  *       Repeat...
 ð        the string ' ' that many times for each
   \\+    Append a backslash to each

j flag: join on newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 42 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,s="\\\n":n*s and s+f(n-1,' '+s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIU@n2FYpJiYmT8kqT6tYITEvRaFYO00jT9dQR11BXbtY839BUWZeiUaahomm5n8A)

-2 bytes thanks to @ovs

Comment: [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIU@n2FYpJiYmT8kqT6tYITEvRaFYO00jT9dQR11BXbtY839BUWZeiUaahomm5n8A) by removing the need for the `or ...`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 13 bytes

```
.+
$* 
 
$`\¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRUuBS4FLJSHm0Lb//00A) Note: Trailing spaces on lines 2 and 3. Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert the input to a string of spaces.

```
 
$`\¶
```

Output each prefix of the string followed by a `\`, on its own line.

This program outputs two trailing newlines, one from the code, one from Retina 0.8.2's default output. The latter can be suppressed at a cost of 2 bytes by changing the third line to `` \` `` . Alternatively the following 14-byte Retina 1 program outputs no trailing newlines:

```
.+
* 
L$` 
$`\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0@bS0uBy0clQYFLJSHm/38TAA) Note: Trailing spaces on lines 2 and 3. Explanation: Much like the Retina 0.8.2 program, except the repetition operator is simply `*` and the list matches command only inserts newlines between the substitutions.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>26</s> 21 bytes

thanks [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper) for challenging my answer

```julia
!n=" ".^(0:~-n).*"\\"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/XzHPVklBSS9Ow8CqTjdPU09LKSZG6X9BUWZeSU6enoaihqGBpuZ/AA)

Comment: you have made it look like a 2D language

Comment: [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/XzHP1sCqTjdPr8YuU9dOSUEpLlNLKSZG6X9BUWZeSU6enoaihqGBpuZ/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 25 bytes

```powershell
1..$args[0]|%{' '*$_+'\'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/31BPTyWxKL042iC2RrVaXUFdSyVeWz1Gvfb///8mAA)

thats why i love powershell

Comment: Can't beat it, but here's a fun 27-byte alt `1..$args[0]|%{'\'|% *ft $_}`

Comment: @ZaelinGoodman nice, feel free to post it

Comment: This technically isn't up to spec. [Here's a 2 byte fix with a 1 byte saving](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/31BPT0klsSi9WKlGtVpdQV1LV1clXls9Rr32////JgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 39

```bash
printf %*s\\n $(eval echo {1..$1}\\ \\)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvhfnFqioKurYGjwv6AoM68kTUFVqzgmJk9BRSO1LDFHITU5I1@h2lBPT8WwNiZGISZG8/9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Zephyr](https://github.com/dloscutoff/zephyr), 80 bytes

```
set s to" "
input n as Integer
for i from 1 to n
print s+"\"
set s to s+" "
next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcuxDYAwDAXR3lN8uaWBMdiBhsKBFDiRYyRgeRMKypPuPVL32yKaOBq8MJiy1tOhWBtmddnEKBVDRrJyYOoXlKpl7WTghenHX3avcnnENL4)

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 31 Bytes

```
gets.to_i.times{|i|p' '*i+'\\'}
```

Works in much the same way as the example code but more rubified

Comment: When I try to run this, I get quotes and double backslashes ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/Pz21pFivJD8@U68kMze1uLoms6ZAXUFdK1NbPSZGvfb/f1MA "Ruby – Try It Online")). Can you link me to an interpreter where this works?

Comment: You can fix this by changing `p` (which is "put raw") for `puts`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/Pz21pFivJD8@U68kMze1uLoms6agtKRYXUFdK1NbPSZGvfb/f1MA "Ruby – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Risky](https://github.com/Radvylf/risky), 20 bytes

```
0?+0+_0+0_?+*{*_?+0__?+0+_0+0+_:-+!_/+/
```

[Try it online!](https://radvylf.github.io/risky?p=WyIwPyswK18wKzBcbl9cbj8rKnsqXz8rMFxuX1xuXz8rMCtfMCswXG4rXG5fOi0rIV8vKy8iLCJbNV0iLDFd)

I'm not happy with the byte count.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 57 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>{for(i=0;++i<n+1;){console.log(" ".repeat(i)+"\\")}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAr4SnFSn0bPYSL2IaG@KKShfx7Tbzus81X7H0PdMd1oomm2tEqoBGaiHwzEJpPjzlRikciR5gGztqKMF1QC6YtYzPuSIoydcP)

Answer (score 1):

## Batch, 88 bytes

```
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion&set s=\&for /l %%i in (1,1,%1)do @(echo !s!
set s= !s!)
```

Takes input from the command line.