# Generating an adequate password

Tags: code-golf

## Story

I need to remember a lot of passwords and don't want to use the same one for multiple websites so I came up with a rule, but the rule shouldn't be transparent so what I do is:

- Think of a long word or concept such as `breadpudding`.
- Replace the first letter with the site we are logging into. If we are logging into `google`, our word becomes `greadpudding`.
- Make the first letter uppercase.
- Change the second letter to an `@` sign.
- If the password starts with a non-consonant, add a certain number (such as `1234`); otherwise, add another number (such as `4321`).

Ta da, you now have an adequate password.

This process is arduous though so I need a program to generate this for me based on the following:

## Problem

Given input:

- `a` : the initial word, which is a string and is always lowercase, and is guaranteed to be longer than 3 characters.
- `b` : the site we are logging into, which is a string and is always lowercase, and is guaranteed to be non-empty.
- `c` : the number for non-consonants, which is a positive integer that may have leading zeroes.
- `d` : the number for consonants, which is a positive integer that may have leading zeroes.

Output a string based on above criteria.

## Test cases

Input `a="volvo", b="gmail", c=5555, d="0001"`

`G@lvo0001`

Input `a="sherlock", b="9gag", c=31415926535, d=3`

`9@erlock31415926535`

Input `a="flourishing", b="+google", c=11111, d=2222`

`+@ourishing11111`

## Rules

- `y` is a consonant.
- If you decide `c` or `d` is an integer, you may parse it as such, and leading zeroes can be ignored (`0091` gets treated as `91`).
- Trailing whitespace and newlines are allowed.
- You may output the result to STDOUT or return the result in a function.
- Characters allowed in `a` and `b` are `[a-z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+=-]`.
- You may accept the 4 inputs in any consistent order.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: [Through 20 years of effort, we've successfully trained everyone to use passwords that are hard for humans to remember, but easy for computers to guess.](https://xkcd.com/936/) Strength of password is never determined by how many uppercase/special characters there is in the password.

Comment: @LeakyNun Yes I agree but the amount of character sets allowed makes it harder as well, so imagine if a password box only allowed lowercase letters, that decreases the difficulty of brute-forcing a lot.

Comment: Yes, at a given length inclusion of more types of characters (numbers, uppercase, symbols) increases security, but not exponentially. A long all lowercase letter password is much stronger than a short mixed character type password. According to zxcvbn: 
"4321breadpudding" (10^9) broken in <1s stored as fast hash,
"4321G@eadpudding" (10^11) broken in 8s,
"granny makes great bread pudding" (10^24) broken in centuries,
"Granny, make great bread pudding!" (10^27) broken in centuries. Remember to calculate password difficulty in orders of magnitude, in which case 2 is not a lot!

Comment: @vee_ess How long does `G@anny makes great bread pudding1234` take to get broken, because that's the point of this, take a phrase and add complexity based on easy to remember rules.

Comment: centuries (guesses: 10^28). It's a great exercise for code golf, but it's bad for real passwords since the complexity added is significant for the user and negligible for the attacker.

Comment: @vee_ess Okay but you forget about stuff like what happens when a site you are a user to gets hacked and your email, password combo gets tried on all major sites before you can react, this protects against that as well. Compromising 1 password doesn't compromise them all.

Comment: "How long does G@anny makes great bread pudding1234 take to get broken"? Well, now it's on all the crackz0rd lists so less than 1 second :-P

Comment: @LeakyNun Did you read the flavor text for that xkcd comic..?

Comment: @vee_ess Okay I've fixed the title.

Comment: *distant echo of people crying at Security.SE*

Comment: @Hankrecords Crying? You're all going and writing helpful generator applications for this pattern! Saves us lots of work!

Comment: @Matthew It was just a joke about how there's always conflict there when speaking of passwords :)

Comment: My passwords (when not restricted by arbitrary rules) all have the form of `:cJw:tang)Kinetic/supervisor+sasquatch:`, or `:xTM:western0Mole4Azure4Scan:`, or `:ouX:bag3slats"spinner*Covered:`, etc.... I find them easy to remember, but, even when the attacker knows the form I use, each one still has over 80 bits of entropy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ḣ©Œu;”@o;⁶⁵®eØC¤?
```

A full program, taking the arguments in the order `b`, `a`, `c`, `d`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AT0Awv9qZWxsef//4biiwqnFknU74oCdQG874oG24oG1wq5lw5hDwqQ/////Z21haWz/dm9sdm//NTU1Nf8wMDAx)**

#### How?

The main link is dyadic, taking `b` and `a`, the program inputs are then `b`, `a`, `c`, and `d` (the 3rd through sixth command line arguments), so `c` and `d` are accessed as such.

```
Ḣ©Œu;”@o;⁶⁵®eØC¤?  Main link: b, a           e.g. "gmail", "volvo" (c="5555" and d="0001")
Ḣ                  head b                         'g'
 ©                 copy to register and yield     'g'
  Œu               convert to uppercase           "G"
     ”@            literal '@' character          '@'
    ;              concatenate                    "G@"
       o           logical or with a (vectorises) "G@lvo"
                ?  if:
               ¤     nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
           ®           recall value from register  'g'
             ØC        yield consonants            "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZbcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
            e          exists in?                  1
         ⁶         ...then: 6th arg = 4th in = d   "0001" 
          ⁵        ...else: 5th arg = 3rd in = c   "5555"
        ;          concatenate                     "G@lvo0001"
                   implicit print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 69 bytes

```python
lambda a,b,*c:b[0].upper()+"@"+a[2:]+c[b[0]in"bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYtNDoIwGET3nsJ0BUJMS8UEEhPvgSxahLZS2lp@FC9fPzYmzuZNMm/cOklraOgut6DZwO9sz1KeHpqSV7g@zs61PooTdEUJq7KyTppqG5RBvLl3Qj56PRj39OO0vN7rB9XBeWWmqIvQYvViUYrEwJQG5hAAxpigON79vFG2Xtumh60QTAAoOZG8yM453Q70z@60nb0apTKbmQhrhW6hkS3ADAKH8AU)

Comment: Why not use `b[0]not in"aeiou"` instead?

Comment: @officialaimm because for some godforsaken reason `9` is counted as a non-consonant.

Comment: Yea, the rule in the question does not say anything about the numbers explicitly...

Comment: Save 3 bytes (note: `z` is the maximum char possible): `('a'<b[0])*b[0]not in"eiou"`

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>22</s> <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```
н©u'@I¦¦žN®åiI\}IJ
```

Input taken as `b,a,c,d`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AT8AwP8wNWFiMWX//zDDqMKpdSdAScKmwqbFvk7CrsOlaUlcfUlK//85Z2FnCnNoZXJsb2NrCjMxNDE1OTI2NTM1CjM)

**Explanation** (outdated)

```
¦                     # remove the first char of a
 s                    # swap b to the top of the stack
  н©                  # push the head of b and store a copy in register
    uì                # convert the head to upper case and prepend to a
      U               # store in variable X
       žN®åi          # if the head of b is a consonant
            \}        # discard c
              X«      # concatenate X with c or d
                '@1ǝ  # insert an "@" at character position 1
```

`0è` used in the link as `н` isn't pulled to TIO yet.

Answer (score 2):

## C, <strike>441</strike> <strike>286</strike> 139 Bytes

```
#define o(c)*a[1]==0xc
int main(int b,char** a){printf("%c@%s%s",*a[1],a[2]+2,(*a[1]>97&*a[1]<128)
&!(o(65)|o(69)|o(6F)|o(75))?a[4]:a[3]);}
```

Comment: erm... instead of 21 sets of `argv[1][0]='c'|argv[1][0]='c'|...` where c = consonant, you can easilly reduce this by doing `!(argv[1][0]='a'|argv[1][0]='e'|argv[1][0]='i'|argv[1][0]='o'|argv[1][0]='u')` Reduces score by 264 just by that!

Comment: No, as mentioned otherwise, that allows numbers and other characters

Comment: @muddyfish then you make it `(argv[0][1]>='a'&argv[0][1]<='z'&!(argv[1][0]='a'|argv[1][0]='e'|argv[1][0]='i'|argv[1][0]='o‌​'|argv[1][0]='u'))`. Still shorter by a margin. However there are so many ways to golf this code I don't know where to start... :s

Comment: I am open to ideas :) This is my first attempt at golfing

Comment: Well, you're doing fine! I'm sure it can still be improved, like using a variable instead of using a macro, but yeah, you're starting on the right foot! :) You could probably make good use of [these golfing tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2203/16236)!

Comment: I saved that somewhere, i will look into it in detail when i have the time. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript ES6, 87 bytes

```
(a,b,c,d)=>b[0].toUpperCase()+'@'+a.slice(2)+(/[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]/.test(b[0])?d:c)
```

### Demo

```js
f=
(a,b,c,d)=>b[0].toUpperCase()+'@'+a.slice(2)+(/[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]/.test(b[0])?d:c)

console.log(f("volvo","gmail", 5555, "0001")); //G@lvo0001
console.log(f("sherlock","9gag", 31415926535, 3)); //9@erlock31415926535
console.log(f("flourishing","+google", 11111, "2222")); //+@ourishing11111
```

Comment: I was about to post this. I mean, *literally* this, character by character. Bummer, lol

Comment: @Hankrecords Hehe, we can maybe improve it

Comment: Since `{|}~` are not valid characters, you can replace `/[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]/.test(b[0])?d:c` with `/[ -_aeiou]/.test(b[0])?c:d` for minus 13 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>80</s> 75 bytes

```
^..(.*)¶(.).*
$2@$1
^([ -_aeiou].*)¶(.*)¶.*
$1$2
(.*)¶.*¶(.*)
$1$2
T`l`L`^.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/Tk9PQ09L89A2DT1NPS0uFSMHFUOuOI1oBd34xNTM/NJYqCSIBMkbqhhxwXgQcYhYSEJOgk9CnN7//2X5OWX5XOm5iZk5XKZAwGVgYGAIAA)

Trying out a new language here, takes inputs in the order given in the question

#### Explanation:

```
^..(.*)¶(.).*
$2@$1
```

Create a word which is second word first letter, @ sign, first word from the 3rd character on.

```
^([ -_aeiou].*)¶(.*)¶.*
$1$2
```

If the word starts with a non-consonant, append the first number

```
(.*)¶.*¶(.*)
$1$2
```

If there are still 3 lines left (no substitution in the last step, so it starts with a consonant), append the second number

```
T`l`L`^.
```

Uppercase the first letter

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>105</s> 103 bytes

```r
pryr::f({m=substr(b,0,1);paste0(toupper(m),'@',substring(a,3),'if'(grepl("[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]",m),d,c))})
```

Anonymous function. Evaluates to

```r
function (a, b, c, d) 
{
    m = substr(b, 0, 1)                      #first letter of website
    paste0(toupper(m),                       #concatenate that letter, capitalized,
           "@",                              #an '@',     
           substring(a, 3),                  #the rest of the long string,
           if(                               #and
           grepl("[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]", m)),   #if the first letter is a consonant,
           d                                 #the consonant string/num,
           else c)                           #else the other one
}
```

which is what's on TIO. Please help me golf that regex because I'm terrible at them.

Saved 2 bytes from Giuseppe.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY67bsQgEEV7fwVyAyiDBOs40hYr5T9WKfwATBYbBNjFRvl2Ak6UU0wx98zohpzVrUEFtW9TMm5DZAA0ApoAzRSd0dc5Kyu6obiPMQVSFA5I0P/MDzFJTpLbvZeBrBRQ@97Cn282XR93ZWuUtFESHaS3pL2PbFZs@WSbZ@lgz49yUm/nUoH@fv9uGkXw4ezhMGC9DsZi6AuAOecC0xrHRQbrpkcxrnrQGDrxKvrr5a3veuhORVm3BxOX0qVYL9o5bSUGUYFLgeacfwA)

Comment: you could use `!grepl('[aeiouy]',m)`

Comment: or better yet, `grepl('[aeiouy]',m)` and just swap `c` and `d`.

Comment: [93 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoMwEAXQu2TjDPyF4k4Reo/iIrZRAk0dZpKFlJ59fE/dRS@dpp1@tljbrGr@HnNZ6tlEkpLRhh4D8yzRauqpoHt0MIoYGSHvgQ5N8qHwjCmf7VoDCuOFN/Of3f0G)

`"if"` makes the `if` syntax much neater instead of using `else` or `ifelse`; I also saved `substring` to a variable and put `m` to uppercase immediately to save a byte.

Comment: I tried running your function and ran into two issues: `pryr` is trying to make `substring` an argument; and your `grepl` only finds "not vowels", which isn't the same as consonants. The `"if"` thing I just missed, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I hadn't actually tested it; I didn't realize `pryr::f` wouldn't like that; you could use the regex '[a-z&&[^aeiouy]]' from Kevin Cruijissen's answer?

Answer (score 1):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 81 bytes

```
G=ucase$(_s;,1|)+@@`+_s;,3,_lC||~instr(@bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz`,_sC,1|)|?G+;\?G+;
```

### Explanation

```
Parameters are Website(A$), base word(C$), consonant-number(E$), and nonsonant-number(F$)
G=                           SET G$ to
 ucase$(      )              the upper-case version of (also works for '9gag', '+google')
        _s;,1|                  the first char of the website A$ read from cmd line
 +@@`                        plus a literal @ (B$)
 +_s;,3,_lC||                plus all characters from base word C$ from 3rd char onwards
~instr(                      IF the second arg to INSTR is in the first
 @bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz`,      with all consonants in the first arg
 _sC,1|                        and the first char of the base word C$ in the second
 )
|?G+;                        THEN print G$ plus the consonant addition
\?G+;                        ELSE print G$ plus the other addition
```

Note that the last two lines appear the same, but the interpreter changes the behaviour slightly 
on each `;`: Whenever it sees the `;` instruction, it creates a new variable (in this case, the 
vars È$`and`F$` are the first available after reading all other literals and cmd line arguments) and
assigns the first not-yet-assigned cmd line paraeter to that variable.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>112</s> <s>99</s> <s>92</s> 87 bytes

```java
(a,b,c,d)->b.toUpperCase().charAt(0)+"@"+a.substring(2)+(b.matches("[a-z&&[^aeiou]].*")?d:c)
```

-13 bytes by taking parameter `b` last instead of second.
-1 byte by removing `y`
-7 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire* (and parameters are in order again)
-5 bytes thanks to *@PunPun1000*

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hU/LasMwELznKxadpNoRdtIU0tAXPTeX0lMoZS0rthJFMpZsKCXf7q6Dcyzdg2YW7czsHrDHuW@0O5THQVkMAd7QuJ8ZgHFRt3tUGrZjC/AeW@MqUHwimE6kuBJ1JaXYkOQ8oydEjEbBFhw8wMAxLVKVlmL@WMjoP5pGt68YNBdS1di@RJ6JhD2zBGXoinBx4wuR8EKeMKpaB852MP9CbXz3KW@YeFL3pRg2Y1TTFZaipsTemxJOdMy07@4TUEyXfIeoT9J3UTb0Fa3jTirOem97z1JWkcwSrqgIsizLmbic9Lc21Lq1Xh1pfl1hRbDMb/PVenG3Wo4my38d9tZ3rQk17UrzSeV9ZTWxfCzCBdVkcp6dh18)

```java
(a,b,c,d)->                     // Method with 4 String parameters and String return-type
  b.toUpperCase().charAt(0)     //  First character of B capitalized
  +"@"                          //  + literal "@"
  +a.substring(2)               //  + A excluding first two characters
  +(b.matches("[ -_aeiou].*")?  //  If B starts with a consonant:
    d                           //   + D
   :                            //  Else:
    c)                          //   + C
                                // End of method (implicit / lambda with single return)
```

Comment: `y` is a consonant so you can drop the `y` in your regex for 1 byte.

Comment: `(a,b,c,d)->` is shorter than `a->b->c->d->`. Currying is only helpful for 2 parameters. For 3, currying is the same as no currying. For 4 and above, no currying is shorter.

Comment: `(a,b,c,d)->b.toUpperCase().charAt(0)+"@"+a.substring(2)+(b.matches("[a-z&&[^aeiou]].*")?d:c)` is 92 bytes long. Also, it uses the parameters in proper order (which confused me at first :-( ).

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Thanks. Second time I make that mistake regarding the currying with four parameters.. And first `toUpperCase()` and then `.charAt(0)` is indeed shorter.. Not sure how I've missed that. (And the different order was to allow `(b=...)`, which wouldn't be possible if it isn't the last parameter with currying, because then it had to be `final` / was implicit `final`.)

Comment: Since `{|}~` are not valid characters, you can use `[ -_aeiou]` for non consonants and swap `d` and `c` for minus 5 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 76 bytes

```
(a,b,c,d)=>b[0].toUpperCase()+'@'+a.slice(2)+(/[aeiou\d_\W]/.test(b[0])?c:d)
```

I would have added this as a suggestion as an improvement to [Weedoze's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/127648/generating-an-adequate-password/127702#127702), but it seems like I can't comment on it since I mostly lurk

Answer (score 1):

## [C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/csharp), 111 bytes

```
(a,b,c,d)=>Char.ToUpper(b[0])+"@"+a.Substring(2)+(b.IndexOfAny("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz".ToCharArray()==0)?d:c);
```

Checking the consonant is particularly expensive with no direct regex capability on the `string` type.

Answer (score 1):

## [F#](http://fsharp.org/), 157 bytes

```
let f(a:string)(b:string)c d=System.Char.ToUpper(b.[0]).ToString()+"@"+a.[2..]+(if((Seq.except['e';'i';'o';'u']['b'..'z'])|>Seq.contains b.[0])then d else c)
```

F# is still very new to me so there are probably better approaches to this.

Answer (score 0):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 25 bytes

```
ldvjr@Ç^[aeiou]ü^Á/j

DÍî
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/PyelLKvI4XB7XHRiamZ@aezhPXGHG/WzuLhcDvceXvf/f2puYmYOV1l@Tlk@l4GBgSGXKRAAAA)

Takes arguments in the buffer in order:

```
website
word/phrase
consonant number
non-consonant number
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)), 76 bytes

```
g(){
a=${2:0:1}
c=$4
[[ "aeiou[0-9]" =~ .*$a.* ]]&&c=$3
p="${a^}@${1:2}$c"
}
```

Works in Bash 4:

```
g volvo gmail 5555 0001; echo $p
g sherlock 9gag 31415926535 3; echo $p
g flourishing +google 11111 2222; echo $p
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 73 bytes

```ruby
->a,b,c,d{a.sub(/..(.*)/){b[0].upcase+"@#$1#{b[0]=~/[aeiou_\d\W]/?c:d}"}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcjdCoIwGIDhW5HZgbO1tdTAwOouOpgjvv1okaA4F4TYrS/p6OV5R68@oanqsDsDUUQTMwN1XiWM0oSmmOFZib2kftDg7BZd4w2P/6v6MgH22ft7beqbZBd9MgtaljD4yUWNSO0buqS1k8MyCOQedux6/UIkQmUL7dqM57woD8ciK1bIHw)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 69 bytes

```
(a,b,c,d)=>e=a[0].toUpperCase()+"@"+a.slice(2)+/[AEIOU]/.test(e)?c:d
```

Pretty simple, probably can be golfed