# Spiral out the Alphabet!

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art, alphabet

Look at the following string. Notice a pattern?

```
ABEFNOPEFGH
DC G  Q   I
M  H  R   J
LKJI  S   K
D     T   L
C     U   M
BAZYXWV   N
E         O
D         P
C         Q
BAZYXWVUTSR
```

As some might have noticed, it's basically a spiral of the alphabet, where the distances between rows / columns are gradually increasing by 1 space / newline.

## Rigorous definition

- Let's have a counter **c**, which is initially 0.
- We write out the first **c + 1** letters of the alphabet from left to right: `A`.
- Then, from top to bottom the next **(c + 1)(c + 2)/2** letters (add `B`): `AB`.
- From left to right, the next **(c + 1)(c + 2)/2** (add `C`):

  ```
  AB
   C
  ```
- And from bottom to top, the next **c + 1** letters (add `D`):

  ```
  AB
  DC
  ```
- Reached the end of the cycle. Hence, let's increment **c** (which becomes 1). Then, it starts back from the first step, the only difference being that instead of using the *first **c + 1*** letters of the alphabet, we use the *next **c + 1*** letters, starting from the last element of this cycle (`D` in this case, so we continue with `EFG...`). When `Z` is reached, it cycles back from `A`.

## Task

Given an integer **N** (which is positive for 1-indexing or non-negative for 0-indexing), output the first **N** cycles of the spiral.

## Rules

- You can either use the lowercase or the uppercase alphabet, but your choice must be consistent (only use one of them, mixing is not allowed).
- You can take input and provide output through any of [the standard methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods), in any [programming language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/what-are-programming-languages), while noting that [these loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden by default.
- Acceptable output formats: multiline string, a list of strings representing lines, a list containing multiple lists of characters, each representing one line, or anything else you find suitable. In case you don't choose the first format, it would be nice to include a pretty-print version of your code.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes (in each language) which fulfils the requirements wins!

---

## Test cases

The input integer will be separated by its corresponding output through a newline, and the tests will be separated using dashes. Note that these are 1-indexed.

```
1

AB
DC

--------

2

ABEF
DC G
M  H
LKJI 

--------

3

ABEFNOP
DC G  Q
M  H  R
LKJI  S
D     T
C     U
BAZYXWV

-------

4

ABEFNOPEFGH
DC G  Q   I
M  H  R   J
LKJI  S   K
D     T   L
C     U   M
BAZYXWV   N
E         O
D         P
C         Q
BAZYXWVUTSR

-------
5

ABEFNOPEFGHFGHIJ
DC G  Q   I    K
M  H  R   J    L
LKJI  S   K    M
D     T   L    N
C     U   M    O
BAZYXWV   N    P
E         O    Q
D         P    R
C         Q    S
BAZYXWVUTSR    T
R              U
Q              V
P              W
O              X
NMLKJIHGFEDCBAZY

------

6

ABEFNOPEFGHFGHIJSTUVWX
DC G  Q   I    K     Y
M  H  R   J    L     Z
LKJI  S   K    M     A
D     T   L    N     B
C     U   M    O     C
BAZYXWV   N    P     D
E         O    Q     E
D         P    R     F
C         Q    S     G
BAZYXWVUTSR    T     H
R              U     I
Q              V     J
P              W     K
O              X     L
NMLKJIHGFEDCBAZY     M
S                    N
R                    O
Q                    P
P                    Q
O                    R 
NMLKJIHGFEDCBAZYXWVUTS
```

Comment: The testcases should be n=1,2,3,5,6, I think.

Answer (score 9):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 31 bytes

```
Ｆ⮌…⁰ＮＢ⁺²⊘×ι⁺³ι⭆α§α⁺λ÷×ι⊕×ι⁺⁹⊗ι⁶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZczPCsIwDAbwV8kxQgRRUMSTsoM7KDJ9gW6Ls9A/o2vL3r6uvXgwl4QvH7/uI1xnhUrpbR1gw5HdxNgIMzBuCGozBn8PumWHq2XgYmd8qDDhluAqVOQeX1LzhJKg5DsCmZsET@@kGW5iREFw9rXpec5nqals@0pG2fNPqE3nWLPxf@yRoLKhVcuj8Iu/L/uU0iGto/oC) Link is to verbose version of code. Note: The deverbosifier outputs a trailing separator for some reason. Explanation:

```
Ｆ⮌…⁰ＮＢ
```

Draw boxes in reverse order of size (largest to smallest).

```
⁺²⊘×ι⁺³ι
```

Calculate the size of the box.

```
⭆α§α⁺λ
```

Draw the border of the box using a rotated alphabet.

```
÷×ι⊕×ι⁺⁹⊗ι⁶
```

Calculate the letter that would appear at the top left of the box (0-indexed).

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 176 bytes

```python
n=input()
k=n*-~n/2+1
a=eval(`[[' ']*k]*k`)
x=y=z=0
for s in range(4*n+4):exec s/4*(s/4+1)/2*"if'!'>a[y][x]:a[y][x]=chr(z%26+65);z+=1\nx+=abs(2-s%4)-1;y+=s%2-s%4/3*2\n"
print a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYfdCoIwGEDv9xRLEPeDLJd6oXy9iAqu0BTjU5zF9KJXN4ngcA5nWpduRL3vCD1Or4VxMgCK8INKy4gYaN7myeqiCGhQieGg5sTBChucSTvO1NIe6Wzw0bBYoIx51rjmTq2KBTskI6608Po2OAVXU6xV4arsX7h3M9t8nco04fkmISrRSTA3y3Ro/ZiHUb5KsP7v1EXoEj0yzT0u1Ox78gU)

### Explanation

We construct an empty array of spaces of the right size, then move over it like this, starting in the top-left corner:

- 1 step →, 1 step ↓, 1 step ←, 1 step ↑
- 3 steps →, 3 steps ↓, 3 steps ←, 3 steps ↑
- 6 steps →, 6 steps ↓, 6 steps ←, 6 steps ↑
- 10 steps →, 10 steps ↓, 10 steps ←, 10 steps ↑
- …

Every time we find a blank cell, we put a letter there and cycle to the next letter in the alphabet.

In the code, `s%4` is the direction (→↓←↑), and we step this many times:

```python
TriangularNumber(s/4) = s/4*(s/4+1)/2.
```

### Golf opportunities

- Is there a shorter way to map `s%4` to `1,0,-1,0` than `abs(2-s%4)-1`?
- Is there a shorter way to map `s%4` to `0,1,0,-1` than `s%2-s%4/3*2`?

### Credits

- Mr. Xcoder saved a byte.

Comment: +1 Wow, this is just brilliant. Took me a while to figure out how it works. I found a shorthand for `21/(s%4+3)%3-1`: `s%2-2*(s%4>2)` ([179 bytes](https://tio.run/##LczNCoJAFEDh/TzFJIjzg5gXdaFcX0QFJ7EU4yqOhbro1U0iOPDtzrQt3UhwHIQ9Ta9FSDYgKf9DAeiQGWzf5inqovC4V6nhrJZsxQ13vLL7OHPLe@KzoUcrIkUybde2ETaIdCjVT5ABKKe/excvN8VWFWuV/sWmm8XuQqKTWGa7xrCkVaO5WQG@dSPph9mm0brgwzlzoxxkSQ6b5p4Wbo4j/gI)). It might still be golfable though

Answer (score 4):

## C,  <s>305</s>  281 bytes

*Thanks to @Mr. Xcoder for saving four bytes!*

```
#define L(x,y)l[x][y]=a++%26+65;
#define F for(
c,i,j,a,p;f(n){char**l=calloc(8,i=a=n*n*4);F;i--;memset(l[i],32,a))l[i]=malloc(a);F c=a=p=i=0;c<n;++c){F i=p;i<c+p+!c;)L(j=0,c+i++)F p=i;j<=-~c*(c+2)/2;)L(j++,c+i)F;c+i-1;)L(j-1,c+--i)F i=0;i<=c;)L(j+~i++,0)}F i=0;i<j;)puts(l[i++]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY/BasMwDIbveQqvY2BFNkuyrRsovubUNyg5GC3ZFBI3tB20lPbVMyelOhjx8f0/Mtsf5ml6/m5aCY3a6JM5Q7891dtz7TziS7HG9QclD6FS7W6vEzZiOuPNSK0OcOFfv0/T3rHv@x3rLyPOu5CG9B2oIrGWhmY4NEfdb6U2b4XxAPPqhnvAR01xzIxOXEZcBkJkuFRK3EhSMo74xAQb3bnMMAoiVCrK1JXO3jjVjAW8FouBOBtQUXxtviCbR2RthGrul9Ldy/AWm0wG1wfvCMa/42G@E7EGuk4SjmrwEjQkl0TFif9XeqbiclJSfpJCFKOW3GoFsFiLqQUouU7/)

Comment: First time I see a `#define` for `for(` (that actually saves bytes). +1 from me. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>262</s> <s>260</s> <s>254</s> 245 bytes

```python
lambda n:[[[' ',chr(65+(4*(i<j)+sum((i<j)*8+2+I*[5,9][i<j]+sum(2*R(I))for I in R(S(i,j)-1))+[i+j,-i-j][i<j])%26)][max(i,j)==S(i,j)*-~S(i,j)/2or i*j<1]for i in R(1+n*-~n/2)]for j in R(1+n*-~n/2)]
R=range
S=lambda x,y:int((8*max(x,y)+1)**.5+.99)/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU@7joMwEOzzFW5O3vUaIqwjgij@AFpSOhTcg4stMBGXSEmTX@eMSXfVzs7Mzmgvj@t59Gru9Gnu2@Hjq2V@b4zhjMvP8wS7nOBdgD04pN/bABGJghRVwuSybEwgmigpUUOF2I0Tq5j1rIYjWOkwyRDJWHIysYlbD/BN7bAxQ3uPFq1Xq0ieK9iqkGKFO2TNkmfXvIx8cPitwsi6f@ym1lPrf743R/165i4fe@uvAIVYysKKlKEQaU5pWYae@TIFnfGT56kbrQf@mn38pF86OigQ5z8)

New method with more maths!

Returns a list of char-lists.

---

Old version:

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>322</s> <s>321</s> <s>308</s> 298 bytes

```python
R=range
n=input()
w=1+n*-~n/2;r=[w*[' ']for _ in R(w)];r[0][0]='A';l=R(1,w*w*9);c=lambda:chr(65+l.pop(0)%26)
for i in R(n+1):
 w=1+i*-~i/2;W=w-i
 for x in R(W,w):r[0][x]=c()
 for y in R(1,w):r[y][w-1]=c()
 for x in R(1,w):r[w-1][w+~x]=c()
 for x in R(1,w-W):r[w+~x][0]=c()
for l in r:print`l`[2::5]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9Na4QwEEDv@RW5FBNd242wSxuZQ/@CFw8hdK392EA6hmAZvexft0YvLRTm9h7zZsI8XgeslqWB2OHnO0NwGL5HIRmBKjAvb/hQ1REM5Sbjmf0YIn/hDnkjSNo6mqNdB7LnrPbQCHWgnPInWffgu6/Xt0731yjOp8LfhyGIo7yrzpKlJW5fgoWSmvEUc2vMrbEWqHSMJ2napfZAUm@pyUK/3rbBeYdqh7M1VKpfePqDEzNU3KZ/jbLdnITTN8lIgk9C1CE6HC/@YiqtT3ZZHn8A)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Isn't just `.49` sufficient enough in that case, or does it fail for very big inputs?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Not sure, but this works for sure, [260 bytes](https://tio.run/##NY67boMwFIZ3nsJLxTm2ITUqUUDxA7CS0fJAb@RYxSCXSMmSV6d2m47/7dO/3Nbz7Ktt63UY/PiRjfprmF7fB@ZbJTwv7n5XZad/8ypvLfkV4MCn4QpRolDIeVmLsmkwVoPuYQTyy2UFRMw@58AcI89Cu4Q4zfPSzeTB5CyXb@cA@1rACwc6OhTflwmMqaR6tiYaVnTc1LJ5iJRWvIcOMVG7RO3hBCQdFgotCkPCyYIK97fAp2qP1qSnqSOU1uOjjxFA3B2VTSj6PYjbdvgB).

Comment: I don't know Python that well, but is it possible to make an inline-variable for `i<j`, since you are using it four times?

Comment: [245 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZU@7joMwEOzzFW5O3vUaIqwjgij@AFpSOhTcg4stMBGXSEmTX@eMSXfVzs7Mzmgvj@t59Gru9Gnu2@Hjq2V@b4zhjMvP8wS7nOBdgD04pN/bABGJghRVwuSybEwgmigpUUOF2I0Tq5j1rIYjWOkwyRDJWHIysYlbD/BN7bAxQ3uPFq1Xq0ieK9iqkGKFO2TNkmfXvIx8cPitwsi6f@ym1lPrf743R/165i4fe@uvAIVYysKKlKEQaU5pWYae@TIFnfGT56kbrQf@mn38pF86OigQ5z8) by golfing `+1==1+` from my previous method

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 177 +2 (-nl) = 179 bytes

2 bytes saved thanks to Xcali

```
sub n{chr 65+$c++%26}@O=(n);while($,++<$_){$_.=$"x$,for@O;push@O,($"x length$O[0])x$,;$O[0]=~s/ /n/eg;s/ $/n/e for@O;1while$O[-1]=~s/.*\K /n/e;s/^ /n/e for reverse@O}print for@O
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##NczdCoIwGMbxc69ixBto8zv0ZA0872AX0IeQLCfIlE0rELv01lI6@/Pye96eqzYzUFHwaUyMHm9ITpVQKM8wVBhv03wuGHWlR56iabkLPsYHKL0JypDC5gX@vVMFI/2oRcF8155Qy2U9CGCn@OJZQJaibx2hSEa8JjbgV2idJstni4JkUeHufFykhVf0h0jxB1eaF2zuVSOHdWxM4qTO3sk@XT80ndQmkO0X)

Comment: You can save a byte by using `-1` instead of `$#O`.  Also using `$,` instead of `$n` will let you remove the space before `for` in `$_.=$"x$n for@O`

Comment: thank you, i was looking for other improvements but could not find for the moment

Comment: saved 2 more bytes changing regex `s/ (?=\S)/n/e` to `s/.*\K /n/e`

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 47 bytes

```apl
(⎕a⍴⍨≢i)@i⍴∘''⊃⌈/i←∪+\↓1⍪⊃⍪⌿(+\⍳⎕)⌿¨⊂⍪∘-⍨∘.≠⍨⍳2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob2pm/qO2CYZcjzra0/5rAPmJj3q3POpd8ahzUaamQyaI0zFDXf1RV/Ojng79TKDaRx2rtGMetU02fNS7CiQMJHv2awCFejcDtWsCOYdWPOpqAol3zNAFGdUxQ@9R5wIQq3ez0X@gTf/TuMwA)