# VEVO User Account Checker

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem

We often see music videos on Youtube. Many Youtube channels that host music videos are "powered by VEVO". Those can be easily identified by both embedding VEVO at their video thumbnails and appending VEVO to their channel name.

Now write some code to test whether a string given by user is a VEVO user account or not.

Requirements for valid VEVO user account strings:

- Must only contain uppercase, lowercase, and digit characters. (no whitespace or punctuation)
- Must not exceed 80 characters length.
- Must have "VEVO" substring at the end of string

Test cases:

Valid inputs:

```
AdeleVEVO
ConnieTalbotVEVO
SHMVEVO
justimberlakeVEVO
DJMartinJensenVEVO
test123VEVO
```

Invalid inputs:

```
syam kapuk
jypentertainment
Noche de Brujas
testVEVO123
```

Of course, because this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), I'm looking for the shortest code using any programming language.

Comment: Nice first question! +1

Comment: test-cases: `VEVO` and `ūņīčōdēVEVO`

Comment: other suggested test cases: `test123VeVo` and one with more than 80 characters

Comment: You should wait a lot longer before accepting a best answer; the question has only been up for an hour and there are plenty more languages that people might answer in!

Comment: What's considered acceptable output here? Would `0` for valid and another/any other number for invalid be allowed?

Comment: Another suggested test case: `test123 VEVO` (ends with VEVO but contains whitespace)

Comment: Alternatively, it is even better if you don't accept an answer at all, so that it is more a competition between answers in each language, rather than between languages.

Comment: "uppercase, lowercase, and digit characters" requires defining (I would assume (as, I believe, all have done already) that you mean A-Za-z0-9; but it could mean anything that may be uppercased or lowercased, for example `ạ` and `Ạ` and digits in other alphabets, for example `九` (9).

Comment: If you're going to accept any answer, please accept the shortest (the winner), rather than an arbitrary answer.

Comment: Can I invert the the valid/invalid and return True for an invalid string and false for a valid one?

Comment: Downside of accepting the Fish answer after only an hour: its the second *longest* answer that's currently available and most definitely not the winner...

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 45 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to Rod. -2 bytes thanks to ovs.*

```python
lambda s:len(s)<81*s.isalnum()<'VEVO'==s[-4:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY89b4NADEB3foU3oGoqJelQoTAkbaUoUtqhVZYkgwlGObjzofMx8Osp0CJRT/bzx5Pr1t8tr7oivXQaTZYjSKKJI4k3L8sHeVKCmhsTxZvw9H76DNNUzovn5Np5Ei@QwjmAPkJp0UCFdVOFj7@kbGtiT86jYtNnE/@wtztBTrBzTYky4eHeYFiu1hPa5qRptP6BV8us6Bt1Zv2cf@2P87JsxCuTkdNY/dt/OxzRecUHYiGedwZ7bx5RcA2CwjpQoBjGN5NxqHaKPRSRirsf)

A regex solution turns out to be longer.

```python
lambda s:re.match('^[^\W_]{0,76}VEVO$',s)
import re
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/) v2.0a0, <s>20</s> 16 bytes

Returns `1` for valid or `0` for invalid. `[\l\d]` would also work in place of `[^\W_]` for the same byte count.

```
è/^\w{0,76}VEVO$
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=6C9eXHd7MCw3Nn1WRVZPJA==&input=InRlc3QxMjNWRVZPIg==) | [Check all test cases](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=y+gvXlx3ezAsNzZ9VkVWTyQ=&input=WyJzeWFtIGthcHVrIiwianlwZW50ZXJ0YWlubWVudCIsIk5vY2hlIGRlIEJydWphcyIsInRlc3RWRVZPMTIzIiwiQWRlbGVWRVZPIiwiQ29ubmllVGFsYm90VkVWTyIsIlNITVZFVk8iLCJqdXN0aW1iZXJsYWtlVkVWTyIsIkRKTWFydGluSmVuc2VuVkVWTyIsInRlc3QxMjNWRVZPIl0KLVE=)

**Explanation**: `è` counts the number of matches of the RegEx in the input. In Japt, the `\w` RegEx class doesn't include underscore.

Comment: Nice one. Best I could do without regex is [`;¥oB+mc)¯80 ©"VEVO"¥Ut4n`](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=O6VvQittYymvODAgqSJWRVZPIqVVdDRu&input=InRlc3QxMjNWRVZPIg==)

Comment: @ETHproductions, nice trick with `B+mc` :) By the way, if Japt2 had a character class for `[A-Za-z0-9]`, we could beat Retina here! Might even be worth overriding `\w` & `\W`.

Comment: Heh, I think I was actually planning to do that originally... I should get back to work on Japt in general :P

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>27</s> <s>36</s> <s>34</s> 31 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Neil and 3 bytes thanks to @Shaggy*

```js
s=>/^[^\W_]{0,76}VEVO$/.test(s)
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

s=>/^[^\W_]{0,76}VEVO$/.test(s)

console.log(f('syam kapuk')) // (INVALID)
console.log(f('jypentertainment')) // (INVALID)
console.log(f('Noche de Brujas')) // (INVALID)
console.log(f('testVEVO123')) // (INVALID)
console.log(f('AdeleVEVO')) // (VALID)
console.log(f('ConnieTalbotVEVO')) // (VALID)
console.log(f('SHMVEVO')) // (VALID)
console.log(f('justimberlakeVEVO')) // (VALID)
console.log(f('DJMartinJensenVEVO')) // (VALID)
```

Comment: Doesn't `\w` match `_`s as well?

Comment: I think `((?!_)\w)` saves 2 bytes.

Comment: Would `[^\W_]` work for a [3 byte saving](https://tio.run/##jc7LasJAFIDhfZ9iFkISUOMF2pUFq4KKl0VLuqi1HJOjTjI5E@ZMBCk@e2wWbmphuvsX3@JP4QQcG1nYFukEq/2g4sFzuP3Ybt6/Pr87zafHSzSJ1o2wbZGtz0EVa2KtsK30wd/7Hp8hFxkUZeYFgQhD4c9W0XAxGwcPv2R6LpAsGguS8p9y@ZWOjygSFC@mTIFdvP6rV7u9vosOE1RY2xv8m400kcQ3UDtt3fp1unSjtGQr8x0aBdk/DsbzJRgraY7ESPe@ugI)?

Comment: @Shaggy Heck. For some reason, I was thinking such characters classes were not working within character sets. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't JS have any way of skipping the lambda? Like `/^[^\W_]{0,76}VEVO$/.test` or something?

Comment: @totallyhuman Indeed, this is a function that is equivalent to the function in this answer, but 6 bytes shorter…

Comment: @Xufox I'm not sure what the consensus is. We could do `(new RegExp).test.bind(/^[^\W_]{0,76}VEVO$/)`, which indeed gives a function that can be called in a standard way. But how would you use (and re-use) `/^[^\W_]{0,76}VEVO$/.test`?

Comment: @Arnauld Well, `/^[^\W_]{0,76}VEVO$/.test` is an expression that evaluates to a function which you can directly use like this: `/^[^\W_]{0,76}VEVO$/.test("TestVEVO")` or `(/^[^\W_]{0,76}VEVO$/.test)("TestVEVO")`. You can save it in a variable `f=/^[^\W_]{0,76}VEVO$/.test;` and use `f("TestVEVO")`, but as far as I know, this assignment is optional in terms of code golf, so you can just skip it.

Comment: @Xufox No, we can't save it in a variable, because _test_ would lose its _this_ context (hence the need to _bind_). This is why it's quite special and not equivalent to the function in this answer.

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 51 bytes

-10 bytes thanks to @Ismael Miguel for using `<?=` instead of `<?php echo`! and removing the closing tag

```php
<?=preg_match("/^[^\W_]{0,76}VEVO$/",fgets(STDIN));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62oCg1PT43sSQ5Q0NJPy46LiY8PrbaQMfcrDbMNcxfRV9JJy09taRYIzjExdNPU9P6///0NJAMAA)

Thanks for the other answers so I didn't have to write the regex!

Comment: Instead of `<?php echo`, you can do `<?=preg_match("/^[^\W_]{0,76}VEVO$/",fgets(STDIN));`.

Comment: You're welcome. You can leave out the closing PHP tag. Quoting the documentation: "If a file is pure PHP code, it is preferable to omit the PHP closing tag at the end of the file." (http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php). This should save you 2 more bytes. Also, instead of `[^\W_]`, just use `\w`, which is the same as `[a-zA-Z_]`.

Comment: Thanks as well, I have a few answers to update now!

Comment: You're welcome. One advice: reading the documentation and getting familiar with it will help a lot.

Answer (score 3):

## [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/), 47 bytes

```apl
{0::0⋄(∧/(1(819⌶)t)∊⎕A,⎕D)∧77>≢t←,∘'VEVO'⍣¯1⊢⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RqAysrg0fdLRqPOpbraxhqWBhaPurZplmi@aij61HfVEcdIOEC5Cw3N7d71LmoBKhF51HHDPUw1zB/9Ue9iw@tN3zUtehR79ZaoHnqaYnZqQpgKa409eLKxFyF7MSC0mwQLyM1Jyc/vjy/KCcFpiCrsiA1ryS1qCQxMy8XyAKJ@eUnZ6QqpKQqOBWVZiUWg4RKUotLQFoMjYxB3LLUsnxq4XyIU4B@BPrL0EBfXRdkg2NKak4qzJFgd8M4zvl5eZmpIYk5SfklMLFgD1@4h0qLSzJzk1KLcoDhABN08fJNLCrJzPNKzStOzYOJUtMXMDNBAQUMJDAXAA)

A pure regex solution is [32 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wR19UedCzXU4zQ07BXjNWPKNasNdMzNasNcw/xV1B/1TS1SV9cEqlRPS8xOVQCJqnOlqRdXJuYqZCcWlGaDeBmpOTn58eX5RTkpMAVZlQWpeSWpRSWJmXm5QBZIzC8/OSNVISVVwamoNCuxGCRUklpcAtJiaGQM4palluVTC@dDnAL0AdCThgb66rogGxxTUnNSYY4EuxvGcc7Py8tMDUnMScovgYkFe/jCPVRaXJKZm5RalAMMB5igi5dvYlFJZp5Xal5xah5MlJq@gJkJCihgIIG5AA), but also is much more boring than this approach.

```apl
{0::0⋄(∧/(1(819⌶)t)∊⎕A,⎕D)∧77>≢t←,∘'VEVO'⍣¯1⊢⍵} a dfn with right arg '⍵'
 0::0⋄                                          on error, return 0
                                 ,∘'VEVO'       a train that appends VEVO
                                         ⍣¯1    apply it -1 times
                                             ⍵  on '⍵'
                                                and error if impossible (which returns 0)
                               t←               save on variable 't'
                              ≢                 get the length of that
                           77>                  if that's smaller than 77
                          ∧                     and
         (1(819I)t)                              [for each of] 't' uppercased
                   ∊⎕A,⎕D                        is it in the uppercase alphabet concatenated with the digits
       ∧/                                        reduced by and
```

Comment: Instead of using `⍣¯1` to check for `VEVO` and needing the dfn guard, you can do `'VEVO'≡¯4↑⍵`. Moving things around a bit gets me `{('VEVO'≡¯4↑⍵)∧∧/⍵∊⎕D,⎕A,(819⌶)⎕A}`

Comment: @Cowsquack yeah, I might have forgotten about `↑`.. There are other better ways to do this challenge though (i.e. Eriks answer) and I like this idea :p

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/what-is-dotnet), 87 + 18 = 105 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY/BTsMwDIbveYqoB5RILBI3pK67jCEhFQ0BWs9patrQNoHYRZvQnr2kG5M4TAJ8sn/7828bnBkfYBzQupo/7ZCgT9nPSuXWvaeMmU4j8gf2yXgMJE3W8A9vK36vrRPyIB@bU9wOzsyRQlx0yUvvuwV/iRLPOBt1ttCqaCCA2GYL0@ig7jAHIgjrcGNrS2IrpVr6wZGQWaZVDq6m5uKUzK@vYr5yFRaWGpFsVpt1Isd45cl@6R36DlQRLEH8AMTkLhLc6Z63@m1oEynTX8dfByTblxA63cLR5a/U7L9U1J2FZ92VniZomj0LPoKuDpz8fnjP9uMX)

```
a=>a.Where(x=>char.IsLetterOrDigit(x)).Count()==a.Length&a.Length<81&a.EndsWith("VEVO")
```

Comment: Wouldn't this fail if the input contains any non-alphanumeric characters?

Comment: @Shaggy You are right, will fix a bit later.

Comment: I have checked with TIO and found that input "ConnieTalbotVEVO" (which should be valid input) was falsely declared as invalid input.

Comment: @BagasSanjaya It is because I put tabs after it in the test case, take the tabs out and it will be the same as the test case above and will work.

Comment: 73+18: `a=>a.All(x=>char.IsLetterOrDigit(x)&x<123)&a.Length<81&a.EndsWith("VEVO")` only ASCII letters or 67+18: `a=>a.All(x=>char.IsLetterOrDigit(x))&a.Length<81&a.EndsWith("VEVO")` with unicode support

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 25 bytes

```apl
≢'^[^_\W]{0,76}VEVO$'⎕S 3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HnIvW46Lj4mPDYagMdc7PaMNcwfxX1R31TgxWM//9Pe9Q2Aa8SrnSgimp1IHjUu@pR71YgCWRbKUC4U9OAQrVcXEC1QGXqnn5hjj6eLgolqcUlxeowUXUurnT14srEXIXsxILSbHUgL6uyIDWvJLWoJDEzLxfIAon55SdnpCqkpCo4FZVmJRaDhEDmgBxjaGSszoUwDspwTEnJLMnMz0vMUcBjMcgcA6ABJqZm5haWVGCBHITFNTgd4JiSmpMK0ZSu7pyfl5eZGpKYk5RfAhML9vCFMbNKi0syc5NSi3ISs@F6XLx8E4tKMvO8UvOKU/NgoiCbgA7C4RqksMHpMJhJ1AwdsJkA)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 83 bytes

```c
c,i;f(char*s){for(c=i=0;s[i];c+=!isalnum(s[i++]));c=i<81*!c*!strcmp("VEVO",s+i-4);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY8/a8MwFMT3fApZUJBsB5q2Q0H10H9QAmmHhixtBkV@bp5tSUaSCyHks7tKh061t@Pux713av6l1DCoHEXF1F661PNjZR1TBRaXwn/gVqisSNDL1vSaRSPLtpyLmN/dLtJEpYkPTumO0c3z5o3mPsP5DRenAU0gWqJh3xZLTo4zQjoXzYrRi/LT0JxE5Q9Sk0Z2fUNj6b9IfejABHAhdumoRsFXq/ZASiAPrq@lH@UC@HD@dXF1Pcrcl9DC76Ax4tEag7CW7c6GSfD9ZTWZ170PqHfgWtlMn3xarqQLaJZgPJhJ9Lwx7vtjTrPhBw)

Comment: I don't see any `return` statement, how does this return `c`? Undefined behavior?

Comment: @MDXF This is indeed undefined behavior and an abuse of how gcc uses the same registers for variable assignment and return values (see [tips for golfing in C](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106067/73296) ). This is not portable and does not necessarily work with other compilers (for instance it doesn't work with clang)

Comment: that's *very* impressive. How did you find that out?

Comment: sometimes f("VO" also be true, when before is "VI" stored; or maybe fault

Answer (score 3):

## [Grime](https://github.com/iatorm/grime), 13 bytes

```
e`n{-76"VEVO"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/KzE39/z81Ia9a19xMKcw1zF/p/38zE9OstKCwdA9vU5AIAA)

Nothing fancy here.
Match the `e`ntire input against the pattern: at most 76 alpha`n`umeric characters, followed by the string `VEVO`.
Prints `1` for match and `0` for no match.
I remembered that the last quote could be removed at end of line, but apparently it just causes a parse error.

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>147</s> 125 bytes

```
!\i:0(?^1[::::::"/9@Z`z"!
;>{(?;{(?v{(?;{(?v{(?;{(?v
 ~l1-?!v >       > !|!: !<
;v    ]/~l99*-0(?!;4["OVEV"{-?;{-?;{-?;{-?;1n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/XzEm08pAwz7OMNoKDJT0LR2iEqqUFLms7ao17K2BuAyd5lKoyzHUtVcsU7BTgAA7BcUaRSsFRRsu6zIQP1a/LsfSUksXaLKitUm0kn@Ya5hStS5QOxI2zPv/vyS1uMTQyBgo7Q8A)

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 147 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/XzEm08pAwz7OMFopMSk5JTUtPSMzKzsnNy@/oLCouKS0rLyissrRydnF1c3dw9PL28fXzz8gMCg4JDQsPCIyytDI2MTUzNzC0kBJkStH39621qraWtFe15Crzi7HUNdesYzLukwBBPSBApaWWrpAyxStTaKV/MNcw5Sqde2tkbFhHpdC7P//R1cfbTuy@kjv0d6UI5OB6vwB)

This prints 1 if the input string is valid and nothing for an invalid input.

Edit 1: Changed the Alphanumeric checks to use ranges rather than comparing against every character. (saving 22 bytes)

Comment: I don't have the time right now to golf this, but I'm pretty sure you can lose bytes by doing comparisons to character codes. The gist of it would be to reject things less than '0' and greater than 'z' and then reject things between '9' and 'A' as well as between 'Z' and 'a'.

Comment: @cole :- I wasn't at my PC to change this yesterday after the post but you are right, comparisons do cut a bit off. I'm sure if you scan across the code you may be able to drop some extra bytes off.

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, <s>53</s> <s>26</s> 30 bytes

```
[[ $1 =~ ^[^\W_]{0,76}VEVO$ ]]
```

Exit code 0 for VALID results and 1 for INVALID results.

<s>Still working on 80 characters or less.</s>

-27 bytes from removing output, thanks to @KeyWeeUsr

+4 bytes, fixed regex (same as everyone else)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvivrKiflJmnnwRiR0crqBgq2NYpxEXHxYTHx1Yb6Jib1Ya5hvmrKMTG/v//vyS1uMTQyNgEJAQA)

Comment: You can just `echo 1` for true, or just go without any echo. There's no need to echo anything as you still end up with an exit code that you actually check with `&&` and `||`

Comment: Okay, wasn't sure what sort of output (if any) was required. The question didn't really say.

Comment: The idea of 'truthy' is explained here https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2190/16658 and is generally implied universally unless specified as otherwise

Comment: This doesn't output anything on TIO. Also, your RegEx allows underscores, which it shouldn't. And you're not checking for length. We require solutions to be fully functional here, works in progress shouldn't be posted. I'd recommend deleting it until you can fix the problems. (On a related note, why do people upvote solutions that clearly don't work?)

Comment: @Shaggy The output is via exit code.

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>101</s> <s>89</s> <s>83</s> <s>81</s> 94 bytes

Edit: <s>Switched to checking for non-alphanumeric characters rather than for alphanumeric.</s> Switched back cause I forget to check between Z and a. Thanks @Emigna. Rip those lost bytes though

Edit 2: Also, I can totally just get rid of those }}}}. Thanks [Teal pelican](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62009/teal-pelican) for that and finding the problem with TIO

Edit 3: replaced a ~~~ with a p

```
!\i::0(?v:::"/")$":"(*$:"`")$"{"(*+$:"@")$"["(*+?
0/?("S"l/
l/"VEVO"[4pn?$0(6
!\{-?vl?
1/;n0/n
```

<s>I don't know why this won't work on TIO, but it works fine [here](https://fishlanguage.com/playground).</s> The problem was that the {} commands in TIO don't work for an empty list. [Try It Here](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/XzEm08rKQMO@zMrKSklfSVNFyUpJQ0vFSikBxK4GsrWBHAcQJxrEsecy0LfXUApWytHnytFXCnMN81eKNinIs1cx0DDjUoyp1rUvy7HnMtS3zjPQz/v/vyS1uASkyNDIGAA)

#### How It Works

```
!\i::0(?v:::"/")$":"(*$:"`")$"{"(*+$:"@")$"["(*+?
0/....../
......... Checks each input is alphanumeric
...       If any isn't, print 0 and exit with an error
...

...
0/?("S"l/ Checks if there are more than 80 characters
...       If so, print 0 and exit with an error
...
...

...
...
l/"VEVO"[4pn?$0(6 Check if the input is less than 4 characters
...               If so, print 0 and exit with an error
...

...
...
./"VEVO"[4pn?$0(6 Take the last 4 characters of the input into a new stack (first time I've actually used [)
...               Add "VEVO" to the stack to compare
...

...
0/....../n
........V
!\{-?vl?  Check if the last 4 characters are VEVO
1/;n0/n   Print 1 and exit with an error if so, else print 0 and exit
```

For consistency, replacing the ; in the last line with an invalid instruction makes *every* output an error.

Comment: I believe your TIO error might be how it works with ordering on the ending stack split. [TIO LINK HERE](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/XzEm08rKQMO@zMrKSklfSVNFyUpJQ0vFSikBxK4GsrWBHAcQJxrEsecy0LfXUApWytHP48rRVwpzDfNXijapq6vLs1cx0DDjUoyp1rUvy7HnsrYzzLO2M8j7/78ktbgEpA4A) Having a mess around in TIO you can change it to this.

Comment: Thanks @Tealpelican. Fixed that and killed a few more bytes

Comment: You are missing the check for characters between "Z" and "a".

Comment: @Emigna Oops, thanks! Fixed!

Answer (score 2):

### C++, <s>129</s> <s>105</s> 102 bytes

Thanks to other answers that showed me that i can count the number of characters

 -2 bytes thanks to Zacharý

```cpp
#include<regex>
int v(std::string s){return std::regex_match(s, std::regex("[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,76}VEVO"));}
```

[TIO LINK](https://tio.run/##TZBvS8MwEMZft5/iqCAtrDAVFNc6mTqR4RTc3Av/IFl3btnatCSX6Rz97DOJYn0T7nmS@12ey6oqnmfZbo@LLNczhJSXiiSyovvnpRLn@Nn1Fc06HVeDDINnFn/14qd2fPq6bbdOjutJf3IfRAkXBOvQvTUgLuagoq1E0lJAQ3grGGWLULVklNQ721MwLsIItr7HNJVAqAjOrPSC3gxzdPiWlZelEBzHLJ@W1Lijm2EjlloRL6Yoc7b613k1GDJJXAxQKBSNb4cdHB41htqwAlas0qtf3qZCQSjJfLIw1Y97V2YLBLO0C6mXTDUsCzK8wPfqxPe991JCaFPtM@i4ZC6n59aRlZogTSEY28QfnBYQWM2cCQBxbA6JSuekzEbcZbgOWQTnpunhsf8iAoMNrnu3I1tHiRnr17tv)

Comment: Where's TIO link at your answer? I'd like to test your code...

Comment: Forgive me if this is a lack of knowledge of C++. Can you move remove the variable `r`, and just have the regex inside the call to `std::regex_match`?

Comment: There is an unneeded space after the comma

Comment: You can remove the comma the space after the comma.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 21 bytes

```
['^\i{0,76}VEVO'-''=]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JTM5OTfn/P1o9Liaz2kDH3Kw2zDXMX11XXd029r@DVRqXhnpJanEJWFABzDQCsY3BXKhoZX6pQnFBamK2Qk5marG6pkJ0mkJ@aUmsQm5iwX8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 21 bytes

```
žKÃQsg81‹IR4£"OVEV"QP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//6D7vw82BxekWho8adnoGmRxarOQf5hqmFBjw/39JanGJoZExkOsPAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 18 bytes

```
A`\W|_|.{81}
VEVO$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7w3zEhJrwmvkav2sKwlivMNcxf5f//4srEXIXsxILSbK6syoLUvJLUopLEzLxcIIvLLz85I1UhJVXBqag0K7GYqyS1uASkzdDImMsxJTUnFcThcs7Py8tMDUnMScoHy3IFe/iC6azS4pLM3KTUopzEbIhSFy/fxCKge7xS84pT88BCIDOB5oHYAA)

or

```
^[^\W_]{0,76}VEVO$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPy46LiY8PrbaQMfcrDbMNcxf5f//4srEXIXsxILSbK6syoLUvJLUopLEzLxcIIvLLz85I1UhJVXBqag0K7GYqyS1uASkzdDImMsxJTUnFcThcs7Py8tMDUnMScoHy3IFe/iC6azS4pLM3KTUopzEbIhSFy/fxCKge7xS84pT88BCIDOB5oHYAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 75 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to user28667.*

```hs
import Data.Char
f s|l<-length s=all isAlphaNum s&&l<81&&drop(l-4)s=="VEVO"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY69asNQDIX3PIXwYBJoAmk7dIiHNCmUgNOhJUvpoNRK77V1f7iSh0Df3XUMNVjT0XeQzjEoDTF3nXUxJIU9Kq52BtPsAvLLmyWT/1EDUiAzWNlyNHhsHUie8@ZpnedVCnHOy8eFFEV2ejm9ZZ1D66EAh7GEeUzWK6zgsphBP5@QyRUdNBjbJhvQHWT1NZJXStpful6NxjF8G4KK4Dm1NcrIlURvYev7h5FtK2IaGvyTXfDe0gfyOejEeH8tJ3vdilp3psTYTF/sDyUmtf5AXshPrFuHPn9g8NX9AQ)

Comment: -2 bytes if you use `drop(length s-4)` and extract `length s`

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <strike>37</strike> 36 bytes

Pretty simple answer using some lovely regex.
Quite possibly the shortest Java answer I've ever done.
-1 bytes thanks to Neil on the Javascript answer

```java
w->w.matches("((?!_)\\w){0,76}VEVO")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYwxq8IwFIXn5Ffc55TAszjpUNTpjU8HwUVFbmusqWlSmluDlP72GEGnA@ec76vxgVPXKltf7rE06D38o7YDZ9qS6q5YKtgMHBgrnDMKLVRiR522FQSZczZyztq@MLoET0gpHk5foEmOz@9wApTJx74YLAEPs1P@rp6eVJO5nrI2jWSssFklgvyqP84N2ETFMF2FrEEqb8qLiRDrn7M8HoMcZr@L@bj/228nMrKcjzHWvSfdFKozeFfv5QU)

Answer (score 1):

## [Deorst](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Deorst), 22 bytes

```
'^[^\W_]{0,76}VEVO$'gm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0nNLyou@f9fPS46LiY8PrbaQMfcrDbMNcxfRT099////yWpxSWGRsYgEQA)

Just uses the regex found by Shaggy

Answer (score 1):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 17 bytes

```
ø^¨áüä©û,76}VEVO$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///COuEMrDi88vOfwkkMrD@/WMTerDXMN81f5/985Py8vMzUkMScpvwQkBAA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: f85e a8e1 fce4 a9fb 2c37 367d 5645 564f  .^......,76}VEVO
00000010: 24                                       $
```

Compressed regexes for the win!

```
ø                   " Count the number of matches of
 ^                  "   The beginning of the line
  ¨áüä©             "   A letter or number...
       û,76}        "   From 0 to 76 times...
            VEVO    "   Followed by "VEVO"
                $   "   At the end of the line
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>35</s> 29+1(-a) = 30 bytes

*-6 bytes thanks to ETHproductions*

*Added 4 bytes. Didn't see that underscore wasn't allowed.*

This is my first golf, so here's hoping I did it right.

Returns 1 if valid, 0 if not.

```perl
print/^[^\W_]{0,76}VEVO$/?1:0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvRD8uOi4mPD622kDH3Kw2zDXMX0Xf3tDK4P//kNTiEkMjY5DQv/yCksz8vOL/uokA)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You can remove extraneous whitespace to get down to  25 (+1) bytes: `print/^\w{1,76}VEVO$/?1:0`

Comment: `+0` converts match bool into number, rather than `?1:0`, saves 2 bytes. Calling with `-ple` prints `$_` for you. So: `perl -ple '$_=/^[^\W_]{0,76}VEVO$/+0'`. 25 bytes. If you are happy to get  blanks on non-matching lines, `$_=/^[^\W_]{0,76}VEVO$/` is 23 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) -n, 22+1 = 23 bytes

```ruby
p~/^[^\W_]{0,76}VEVO$/
```

Output `0` if true, `nil` if false

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6BOPy46LiY8PrbaQMfcrDbMNcxfRf///8SkZEMjYxCPC8YsgzLj4aIKEAUVVAYYdv/LLyjJzM8r/q@bBwA)

Using the same boring regex as everybody else.

Answer (score 1):

## [Swift 4](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), 113 bytes

```swift
import Foundation;var f={(s:String)->Bool in s.range(of:"^[^\\W_]{0,76}VEVO$",options:.regularExpression) != nil}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VdDdS8MwEADw9/4VZ/GhhTr8QmFSwelEBtOHyXzYh2T2Wm9LLyW56sbY317bjcLMU/LL5e5y7pdSua4qygtjBZ5NyYkSMnz3oyyk8TZw3ZFY4iw8u@8Zo4EYXMcqzjAwadefT@bT6cfnbHse3d7sxv3x26kfmaJJ4bodi1mple2vC4vO1RbCSQxMeldpFBB04iCGiQf18t1G5bBSRbnyo4MsNwWyoBVFnNe71l/N1zdCgtCz5VK5lpt8TQsXl1ctPSSosbEWHg0z4bvSCyPHPnoZHh@XpRPKF2i1Wv17/zQYKivEA2SHfHzTVK8r78mbeV5qLFAzr8M3t/uoop6lBGlAYejtqj8)

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 23 bytes

```
$0~/^[^\W_]{0,76}VEVO$/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fxaBOPy46LiY8PrbaQMfcrDbMNcxfRf///5LU4hJDI2MQFwA)

Outputs the account name if valid, and outputs nothing if it isn't valid

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), 61 bytes

```
import StdEnv
?['VEVO']=True
?[_:l]=length l<80&& ?l
?_=False
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY2xCsIwFAD3fkWmZio4ihgyaAWh4NDSpZTy2sYaeHmRJhX8eZ9BxxvubkIDxM7PGxrhwBJb9/RrFHWcS3plupNt2d5kr5p1MwmHA/YKDS3xIfC43@W50JjpQV0Ag@E6QpKV0KKTJ09kTQM4@viP8Ge6IyyBi5GLa8XnN4GzU/hBOlZ2/AI)

Answer (score 0):

## Google Sheets, 33 Bytes

Anonymous worksheet function that takes input from range `A1` and outputs to the calling cell

```vb
=RegexMatch(A1,"^[^\W_]{0,76}VEVO
```

Comment: Where's the closing bracket?

Comment: @BagasSanjaya that's one of the wonderful things about Google Sheets, it autocompletes unclosed strings and groups. So when this is pasted into a cell and you either click off the cell or press enter GS converts this to `=RegexMatch(A1,"^[^\W_]{0,76}VEVO")` without any feedback to the user and executes

Answer (score -1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 146 bytes

```clj
(fn[u](let[c count](and(<(c u)81)(=(c(filter #(let[i(int %)](or(< 47 i 58)(< 64 i 91)(< 96 i 123)))u))(c u))(clojure.string/ends-with? u"VEVO"))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1NC4JQEEX/ymAEM4sKy0zBaFMbIdq5ERfyfNaEjPA@6Oe/Xra5HLiHe9U0v73RIeAore9w0q5VoGYvrsNeBqxQgaciJTyjwpEnpw2sFo@RxcGaOpwNVpCdgOFYUMQ8i1imPyzziOn@QESeaBmL@X/dWmdYnjstg9182L0u4JPm1jySaFMIIbnW9944llqL1bJUXw)

This would be much shorter using a regex, but I figured doing it manually would be more interesting.

```clj
(defn vevo? [username]
  (and (< (count username) 81)

       ; Filter out the illegal characters, then check if the length is the same as the original string
       (= (count (filter #(let [i (int %)]
                            ; Make sure the char code is in the valid ranges
                            (or (< 47 i 58) (< 64 i 91) (< 96 i 123)))
                         username))
          (count username))

       (clojure.string/ends-with? username "VEVO")))
```

Comment: Any TIO link for testing?

Comment: @BagasSanjaya I can add one in a bit. It seems like adding TIO links are standard now. They were optional last time I used the site frequently, but now everyone's adding them.

Comment: @BagasSanjaya I added a link. Unfortunately TIO seems broken. It can't find the `ends-with?` function, even though that's part of the standard library.