# Write The Shortest Program to Calculate Height of a Binary Tree

Tags: code-golf, binary-tree

The height of a binary tree is the distance from the root node to the node child that is farthest from the root.

Below is an example:

```
           2 <-- root: Height 1
          / \
         7   5 <-- Height 2
        / \   \
       2   6   9 <-- Height 3
          / \  /
         5  11 4 <-- Height 4
```

Height of binary tree: 4

**Definition of a Binary Tree**

A tree is an object that contains a signed integer value and either two other trees or pointers to them.

The structure of the binary tree struct looks something like the following:

```
typedef struct tree
{
  struct tree * l;

  struct tree * r;

  int v;

} tree;
```

The challenge:

**Input**

The root of a binary tree

**Output**

The number that represents the height of a binary tree

Assuming you are given the root of a binary tree as input, write the shortest program that calculates the height of a binary tree and returns the height. The program with least amount of bytes (accounting whitespaces) wins.

Comment: What do languages without pointers take?

Comment: Good question, they take a reference to the instance of the tree object. I think  I might want to provide the implementation of a tree object in that case.

Comment: ...but then my tree object could just have a property, say `h`. Might be better to define a specific structure made just of lists for the purpose of this challenge.

Comment: @T.Salim In the future, please consider posting in the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) first.

Comment: Sure wizzwizz4. Will do.

Comment: So, is a valid representation a list of length 3 `[root_value, left_node, right_node]` where each of `left_node` and `right_node` are also binary trees acceptable? It'll be trivial in many languages, but might be fun in some others.

Comment: As long as it works as a valid binary tree structure, sure.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include what constitutes a valid binary structure? Perhaps a definition like `a tree is an object that contains a value and either two other trees or pointers to them`. A definition that is inclusive of languages without objects would also be nice too.

Comment: Yes, I have added a Definition of Binary Tree section.

Comment: Can we exclude the value part of the tree, since it has no bearing on the challenge itself?

Comment: If not, what values can the value be? The struct has only integers, but can they also be strings or trees themselves?

Comment: I specified that each node must store a signed integer value.

Comment: Can you please add some more test cases?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒḊ’
```

A monadic Link accepting a list representing the tree: `[root_value, left_tree, right_tree]`, where each of `left_tree` and `right_tree` are similar structures (empty if need be), which yields the height.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc7uh41zPz//3@0kU60uQ6IjAUiIDbTiTaFcwwNoUwQByJsqRNtApcHSQAA)**

#### How?

Pretty trivial in Jelly:

```
ŒḊ’ - Link: list, as described above
ŒḊ  - depth
  ’ - decremented (since leaves are `[value, [], []]`)
```

Comment: Jonathon Allen, that is an interesting language you are using. As a newcomer, may you provide a link or a website referral that tutors people how to use Jelly?

Comment: Click the link in the header - it's a golfing Language developed by [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012), one of the site's moderators.

Comment: I wonder how controversial it would be to represent a leaf as `x` instead of `[x, [], []]`...

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer To keep with the "pointer" and "struct" nature of the question I think every node should be of the same form.

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/),  <s>35</s>  33 bytes

Thanks to Arnauld for noicing an oversight and saving 4.

```python
f=lambda a:a>[]and-~max(map(f,a))
```

A recursive function accepting a list representing the tree: `[root_value, left_tree, right_tree]`, where each of `left_tree` and `right_tree` are similar structures (empty if need be), which returns the height.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIdEq0S46NjEvRbcuN7FCIzexQCNNJ1FT83@JbWZeQWmJhiZXQVFmXolCmkaJ5v9oI51ocx0QGQtEQGymE20K5xgaQpkgDkTYUifaBC4PkgAA)**

<sup>Note that `[]` will return `False`, but in Python `False==0`.</sup>

Comment: The same person is allowed to give two different answers to the same question?

Comment: Yeah, of course, golf is a competition at a language level. Even a second entry in the same language is sometimes acceptable, if the approach is very different.

Comment: @Arnauld Guess so (I'd assumed non-integers might be present for some reason)

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>11</s> <s>7</s> 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Δ€`}N
```

-4 bytes thanks to *@ExpiredData*.
-2 bytes thanks to *@Grimy*.

Input format is similar as the Jelly answer: a list representing the tree: `[root_value, left_tree, right_tree]`, where each of `left_tree` and `right_tree` are similar structures (optionally empty). I.e. `[2,[7,[2,[],[]],[6,[5,[],[]],[11,[],[]]]],[5,[],[9,[4,[],[]],[]]]]` represents the tree from the challenge description.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3JRHTWsSav3@/4820ok21wGRsUAExGY60aZwjqEhlAniQIQtdaJN4PIgCQA) or [verify a few more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/c1MeNa1JqPX7r6N3aOv/6GgjnWhzHRAZC0RAbKYTbQrnGBpCmSAORNhSJ9oELg@WUFAAchWiYUqBTBwqAQ).

**Explanation:**

```python
Δ     # Loop until the (implicit) input-list no longer changes:
  €`  #  Flatten the list one level
}N    # After the loop: push the 0-based index of the loop we just finished
      # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Note that although 05AB1E is 0-based, the changes-loop `Δ` causes the output index to be correct, because it needs an additional iteration to check it no longer changes.

Comment: [7 bytes?](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3JRHTWsSDu2pPbTP5v//aCOdaHMdEBkLREBsphNtCucYGkKZIA5E2FIn2gQuD5IAAA "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Comment: @ExpiredData Ah, of course.. Thanks! :)

Comment: [5 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3JRHTWsSYv3@/4820ok21wGRsUAExGY60aZwjqEhlAniQIQtdaJN4PIgCQA)

Comment: @Grimy I thought using the index outside a loop only worked in the legacy code.. :S Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

### Haskell, 33 bytes

```
h L=0 
h(N l r _)=1+max(h l)(h r)
```

Using the custom tree type `data T = L | N T T Int`, which is the Haskell equivalent of the C struct given in the challenge.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfkliSqBCiYKvgo1Cj4AdkhSh45pX8z1DwsTVQ4MrQ8FPIUShSiNe0NdTOTazQyFDI0QQSRZr/cxMz84DaCooy80oUVBQyFIBKIcgHCI00kTimmjCWoaGmgpmmgjlUAKHERBNIWGqClBpp/gcA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 25 bytes

```perl6
{($_,{.[*;*]}...*eqv*)-2}
```

Input is a 3-element list `(l, r, v)`. The empty tree is the empty list.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WkMlXqdaL1rLWiu2Vk9PTyu1sExLU9eo9n9xYqVCGlBWUyEtv4hLQ1OHSwNIKICwIZiDxEMSBXGQZbCoRZP@DwA)

#### Explanation

```perl6
{                       }  # Anonymous block
    ,        ...  # Sequence constructor
  $_  # Start with input
     {.[*;*]}  # Compute next element by flattening one level
               # Sadly *[*;*] doesn't work for some reason
                *eqv*  # Until elements doesn't change
 (                   )-2  # Size of sequence minus 2
```

#### Old solution, 30 bytes

```perl6
{+$_&&1+max map &?BLOCK,.[^2]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WlslXk3NUDs3sUIhN7FAQc3eycff2VtHLzrOKLb2f3FipUKahkq8pkJafhGXX2aODpcGiFQAE4aaQC4qH0kCzEKTxaYDU8l/AA)

Comment: The `&?BLOCK` trick is interesting but it's a [couple of bytes shorter](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/19F0bZaWyVeTc1QOzexQiE3sUBBRVFHLzrOKLb2f3FiJZCnoRKvqZCWX8Tll5mjw6UBIhXAhKEmkIvKR5IAs9BksenAVPIfAA) to assign the block to $!

Comment: @JoKing I don't know. Storing the challenge solution in a volatile global like `$!` or `$/` feels like cheating to me.

Comment: (Ab)using variables like $! and $/ is fairly standard practice for golfing P6.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>35</s>  33 bytes

Input structure: `[[left_node], [right_node], value]`

```javascript
f=([a,b])=>a?1+f(f(a)>f(b)?a:b):0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjOlEnKVbT1i7R3lA7TSNNI1HTLk0jSdM@0SpJ08rgf3J@XnF@TqpeTn46UDIaCGJ1FEDYCETDeaZgHpRjaAgkzIDYHC4KlzOB0pZQTUaxmpr/AQ)

#### Commented

```javascript
f =                       // f is a recursive function taking
([a, b]) =>               // a node of the tree split into
                          // a[] = left child, b[] = right child (the value is ignored)
  a ?                     // if a[] is defined:
    1 +                   //   increment the final result for this branch
    f(                    //   and add:
      f(a) > f(b) ? a : b //     f(a) if f(a) > f(b) or f(b) otherwise
    )                     //
  :                       // else:
    0                     //   stop recursion and return 0
```

Comment: Looks like you can save a byte with `a&&-~`.

Comment: @Shaggy That would lead to [comparisons with _undefined_](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjOlEnKVbT1i5RTU23Lk0jTSNR0y5NI0nTPtEqSfN/cn5ecX5Oql5OfjpQKjo6OlZHAYQN4bSm5n8A).

Answer (score 4):

## C, 43 bytes

```
h(T*r){r=r?1+(int)fmax(h(r->l),h(r->r)):0;}
```

Structure of binary tree is the following:

```
typedef struct tree
{
  struct tree * l;

  struct tree * r;

  int v;

} tree;
```

Comment: 55 bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLLboMwELzzFatUlXBiypsDlOTSY9RbT00PEY8EySXIbFJVlF8v9QOoEsUH45nZmV1pyaxDlg343RR5UUKL/JwhIC8K6Ay4wkuW3DJcMlWNcEmMXnHJcDSRMsqJREtMOkxxw1LBWmtGKNcvTqi7Mtmab1jMSewk/fBQ1Rk75wU8t5hXp6fj2jBk9Oe@qs3LqcqJmkg1xvePVAKADnDlUnF5FBzoqaBsG5xRe33bbul4u1IVmjv7/EnylFFo3qwFMjOk4M@Z/qxFky@YfMGdfuHYL7yjRdArXyS0PjEMBV6KBo@xfrswH0cz/8eGnaa8iZHV3k3Zj8b@hP1rfQ4JNJaf8KpkDAg1iuSQDRcLKc2FmhROpVpGDI/5rl5QEIslRPwHw29Wsv2hHayvPw "C (gcc) – Try It Online") Some C-specific golfing tricks [are here!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2203/tips-for-golfing-in-c)

Comment: @ErikF Or [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZE9b4MwEIZ3fsUpVSWTQPlmgIYsHaNOdGo6RGBiJArIOKmqlL9e6g8gooqH87333HtnyZl5yrKBfbc4xwV0jJ4zBilcNbiJdRUvJBWyrBlcYq2HNB4IStdUv9It3TkbggiiZlLpibypvhMqkmlkx/3wUNZZdc4xPHcsL5snkmiamPZ5LGt0acpcl@tTYO8fW5EBXIFtHIMH1wAbeoOXLAvskb2@7ffGGB1BOXNmnzchVxo5c2fmi5mBAd4805tZOPn8yeff2ReM@4I7LIRe@kLO@ljTpHjBLSORyh2Yj60qt2PBQZXcqSK63X9tP0p7k/aWfB7iKy2uYNEyDgiUCsUjW8p/o0Ar@VJoCmAU4wge80O9MoAgpuv834ffrKiOp24wv/4A)

Comment: Thanks ErikF and Arnauld. I should try out the ternary operator more often instead of if-else-if chains.

Comment: [43 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZFJT8MwEIXv@RWjIiS7dcieQ0LLhWPFKZxaDlGWJlI2OW4Blfx1jJ2tCqoPtt98895YcqSeooiz7yaJkxRaRs8RgwCuCtzEuvAXkkqZVwwuvtJB4PMMBWuKr3RLX4wNEgSnZfiFMkTVXYFJf1KMPd3v@ENeRcU5TuC5ZXFeP2U7RZFZZZhX6FLnMe6HB8AOH1t5A7gC2xhEbCYBHToiSpoG@sje3vd7Mu6GpIIZs8@akNkbBTNnZstMh4A1Z1ozcyefPfnsO/OccZ5zh7nQ9T5XsM5XlF68Jg3LvOFuwLz0oXJbGhyHkjlVZLf5r@1n0NakrSWfQ@xBy8NZtIwBzqBc@ciGit9I0ap/KdQpMJokHjzGx2pFIEMMY/Hr/DdKi/DUcvWTq0X5Bw)

Comment: If your submission relies on flags, can you please add them to the header of your submission?

Comment: Building on @nwellnhof [42 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZFJb4MwEIXv/IpRqko4MWXnACW99Bj1RE9JD4glILHJOGmblL9e12aLqOKD7TffvDeWHCnHKGL0u0niJIWWklNEIYCrBDexLryFJELmFYWzJ3UQeOziZXKwJuhKfPJy8fVNWoZfciYTZVsg3J8EIVfzOvaQV1FxihN4bmmc10/ZVpJEVBnmlXyu8xj1swOg@w9f3ACuQDc65puBQYMO85Kqgjayt/fdDo@7Lihn@uwzJ2T0Rs6MmVki08ZgzpnmzJzJZ00@6848e5xn32EOdL3P4azzJKkXr0lDM3e46zAvbajclgqHoWRMFdFt/Gv7GbQ5aXPJ5xBr0OKwFy1jgD0oRzyyIfw3UnnVvxTqFChJEhce40O1wpDJFCH@6ew3Sovw2DLlkylF@Qc "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 32 bytes

```javascript
f=a=>/,,/.test(a)&&f(a.flat())+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbR1k5fR0dfryS1uEQjUVNNLU0jUS8tJ7FEQ1NT2/B/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmkY0EMTqKICwEYiG80zBPCjH0BBImAGxOVwULmcCpS2hmoxiNTX/AwA)

<s>Using the name `flat` instead of `flatten` or `smoosh` is a great idea for code golf.</s>

Using `[]` for null node in the tree, and `[left, right, value]` for nodes. `value` here is an integer.

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 10 bytes

```
Depth@#-2&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2ar8d8ltaAkw0FZ10jtv6Y1V0BRZl5JdFp0tZGOQrU5EIPoWhAGEWZAbIosYGgI54H5IElLIDZBVgQlamNj/wMA) Takes input as a nested list `{v, l, r}`.

Comment: If `2[7[2,6[5,11]],5[9[4,],]]` is a valid representation of the tree, `Depth` works

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 28 bytes

Using the following data definition:

```
data T a = (:&) a [T a]
```

The height is:

```
h(_:&x)=foldr(max.succ.h)0 x
```

Answer (score 2):

## Scheme, 72 Bytes

```lisp
(define(f h)(if(null? h)0(+ 1(max(f(car(cdr h)))(f(car(cdr(cdr h))))))))
```

More Readable Version:

```lisp
(define (f h)
   (if (null? h)
      0
      (+ 1 
         (max
             (f (car (cdr h)))
             (f (car (cdr (cdr h))))
         )
      )
   )
)
```

Using lists of the form (data, left, right) to represent a tree.  E.g.

````
   1
  / \
  2  3
 /\
 4 5

is represented as: (1 (2 (4 () ()) (5 () ())) (3 () ())

(1
   (2
      (4 () ())
```   (5 () ())
   (3 () ())
)
````

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##K07OSM1N1QWSVf//a6SkpmXmpWqkKWRoamSmaeSV5uTYA9kGGtoKhhq5iRUaaRrJiUUaySlFQFFNTQQXLgQGQIMyiwtyEisVgEapawBFuOAiSjF5SkhcsAJDBQ1NBZAyotQZwVUTVg5TC2YZwznGCCOIMgOo3gSuWZOQif8B)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 51 bytes

```r
function(L){while(is.list(L<-unlist(L,F)))T=T+1;+T}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lU89D4IwEN37Ky5xaQNoWgoGP1bj0Djh5mZEmxBIoMbB@NtrKRoOdbHJvbvevfd6bWyxtsW1OhpdV1Sx@@2iyxPV7bTUraFqFV2rvgo3jLF8nQd8GeQPO4HhCFhFETR1bRawPenzxQAniDCDA7rOXSRe8eKKYeiYDge2cJG6yDA//vB2gDoJAOcgsUACIapbEvxXROjTPNztlfLA@k6COoyo@Fvxun0KUywcefk6w2NnLP8w/lqs73A@8vz1pk8SK98LkIIqwTqMPcoOPT3GrvYJ)

- **Input:** a nested list in the format : `list(ROOT_ELEMENT, LEFT_TREE, RIGHT_TREE)`
- **Algorithm:** Iteratively flattens the tree by one level until it becomes a flat vector : the iterations count corresponds to the max depth.

Inspired by [@KevinCruijssen solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/189241/41725)

---

Recursive alternative :

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 64 bytes

```r
`~`=function(L,d=0)'if'(is.list(L),max(L[[2]]~d+1,L[[3]]~d+1),d)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lU9NC8IwDL33VwQ8uGKn9mPKRO8eijdPKijOj4I60Ame9tdn7JRl04uFl6TJe6/ptSjW@Xqyv1@2mUsvgRXJpM/bbt8O3K17crcssFycN4/ALhZqtcqTjhRY6rLkIuFFC6qjYByGcE3TbATTnTscM5CMEHqwJNchIvKKN1dVQ2RirNgKMUDElK8b3hhIJwKQEgwVGGDMvpYE/zclfBqK2dxaH3jZiUiHM6u/Fe9bUzigwpqXr2M6RmPzh/HXYmVHyprnrzd9MlT5WYDlViE0wrDc8zThFU8)

Redefines the function/operator `'~'` making it able to compute the max depth of a tree stored in a list structure.

The list structure of a tree is in the format : `list(ROOT_ELEMENT, LEFT_TREE, RIGHT_TREE)`

- -2 thanks to @Giuseppe

Comment: why do you use `d=1` and then `d-1` at the end? Couldn't you start at `0`?

Comment: Also I switched `>` to `~` [here](https://tio.run/##lU9NC8IwDL33VwQ8uGKn9mPKRO8eijdPKijOj4I60Ame9tdn7JRl04uFl6TJe6/ptSjW@Xqyv1@2mUsvgRXJpM/bbt8O3K17crcssFycN4/ALhZqtcqTjhRY6rLkIuFFC6qjYByGcE3TbATTnTscM5CMEHqwJNchIvKKN1dVQ2RirNgKMUDElK8b3hhIJwKQEgwVGGDMvpYE/zclfBqK2dxaH3jZiUiHM6u/Fe9bUzigwpqXr2M6RmPzh/HXYmVHyprnrzd9MlT5WYDlViE0wrDc8zThFU8) so the test cases are easier to input

Comment: @Giuseppe: of course...I was missing the obvious ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 bytes

```
@eU=c1}a
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QGVVPWMxfWE&input=WzIsWzcsWzIsW10sW11dLFs2LFs1LFtdLFtdXSxbMTEsW10sW11dXV0sWzUsW10sWzksWzQsW10sW11dLFtdXV1d)

### Original, 9 bytes

```
Î©¡ÒßXÃrw
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=zqmh0t9Yw3J3&input=WzIsWzcsWzIsW10sW11dLFs2LFs1LFtdLFtdXSxbMTEsW10sW11dXV0sWzUsW10sWzksWzQsW10sW11dLFtdXV1d)

Answer (score 1):

## Kotlin, 45 bytes

```
val Tree.h:Int get()=1+maxOf(l?.h?:0,r?.h?:0)
```

Assuming the following class is defined

```
class Tree(var v: Int, var l: Tree? = null, var r: Tree? = null)
```

[Try it online](https://pl.kotl.in/K4PmzcvGl)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 4 bytes

**Solution:**

```
#,/\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/19ZRz9Gw8haw9xaQ8dI01rDDEibAmkdQ0NNTSBtaq0BJC2BAiZAGiik@f8/AA)

**Explanation:**

I think I may have missed the point.

Representing a tree as the 3-item list (parent-node;left-child;right-child), the example can be represented as

```
(2;
  (7;
    (,2);
    (6;
      (,5);
      (,11)
    )
  );
  (5;
    ();
    (9;
      (,4);
      ()
    )
  )
)
```

or: `(2;(7;(,2);(6;(,5);(,11)));(5;();(9;(,4);())))`.

So the solution is to iteratively flatten, and count the iterations:

```
#,/\ / the solution
   \ / iterate
 ,/  / flatten
#    / count
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 29 bytes

```
⊞θ⁰⊞υθＦυ«≔⊕⊟ιθＦΦι∧κλ⊞υ⊞Ｏκθ»Ｉθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYxPC8IwDMXP66fIMYUKTvyDeBqC4Mndyw5lq65Yu63rvIifva7dBIWQ5L38Xspa2LIR2vt86GvsGCzpgcR9YNCN@7WxgAOFF0myvlc3g2dTWvmQxskK86ZFRemEJpE9Ke2kRcUgMxXeGWhKKXxfhnlppRWuseHY0TH4JrlVxuFR9A6D4z0nwFeMAPBd6EHwYqxiUts4gG9@XeBpOuvJGc@RnkP7mVr/hwJNCr946g8) Link is to verbose version of code. Temporarily modifies the tree during processing. Explanation:

```
⊞θ⁰
```

Push zero to the root node.

```
⊞υθ
```

Push the root node to the list of all nodes.

```
Ｆυ«
```

Perform a breadth-first search of the tree.

```
≔⊕⊟ιθ
```

Get the depth of this node.

```
ＦΦι∧κλ
```

Loop over any child nodes.

```
⊞υ⊞Ｏκθ
```

Tell the child node its parent's depth and push it to the list of all nodes.

```
»Ｉθ
```

Once all the nodes have been traversed print the depth of the last node. Since the traversal was breadth-first, this will be the height of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
▐▌µ╡⌂
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=dedde6b57f&i=[2,[7,[2,[],[]],[6,[5,[],[]],[11,[],[]]]],[5,[],[9,[4,[],[]],[]]]]&a=1)

Stax has neither pointers nor null values, so I represent the input like `[2,[7,[2,[],[]],[6,[5,[],[]],[11,[],[]]]],[5,[],[9,[4,[],[]],[]]]]`.  Maybe that's an unfair advantage, but it was the closest I could get.

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, the code looks like this.

```
        The input starts on top of the input stack
Z       Tuck a zero underneath the top value in the stack.  Both values end up on the main stack.
D       Drop the first element from array
F       For each remaining element (the leaves) run the rest of the program
  G^    Recursively call the entire program, then increment
  T     Get maximum of the two numbers now ow the stack
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=++++%09The+input+starts+on+top+of+the+input+stack%0AZ+++%09Tuck+a+zero+underneath+the+top+value+in+the+stack.++Both+values+end+up+on+the+main+stack.%0AD+++%09Drop+the+first+element+from+array%0AF+++%09For+each+remaining+element+%28the+leaves%29+run+the+rest+of+the+program%0A++G%5E%09Recursively+call+the+entire+program,+then+increment%0A++T+%09Get+maximum+of+the+two+numbers+now+ow+the+stack&i=[2,[7,[2,[],[]],[6,[5,[],[]],[11,[],[]]]],[5,[],[9,[4,[],[]],[]]]])

Answer (score 0):

## Julia, 27 bytes

```
f(t)=t≢()&&maximum(f,t.c)+1
```

With the following struct representing the binary tree:

```
struct Tree
    c::NTuple{2,Union{Tree,Tuple{}}}
    v::Int
end
```

`c` is a tuple representing the left and right nodes and the empty tuple `()` is used to signal the absence of a node.

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 42 bytes

```
fun N.c():Int=maxOf(l?.c()?:0,r?.c()?:0)+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYwxDsIwDEXn9hQeY1GhskaUipElDJzAKmpV4RqapBUIcfaQFMGCvfz/ZL/L1XMv4UyeoGFyDoyaiYE1mBoqkIm5gETsH5k1HMRHVGJoJwGzbhTqiKqB7sdWcZ1ArcvCfhOuNsvpQL0osp3TsLeWHtuTt710O3zmWVKP0WrUZxGLX05tmTy7xQfPosakxvwV3g)

Where

```
data class N(val l: N? = null, val r: N? = null, val v: Int = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 18 bytes

Takes input as `[Value, Left, Right]` *or* any permutation of this.

```perl
[paths|length]|max

 paths             # for each path as a list of indexes to follow
                   # to get to an element or array inside the input
                   # e.g. [0,2,1] to represent array[0][2][1]
      |length      # its length
[            ]     # collect into an array
              |max # the maximum of this array
```

[jq play it!](https://jqplay.org/s/nXIfxv-o6C)