# Talk interpreter

Tags: code-golf, interpreter

"Talk" is a baroquified accumulator-based language that is created in response to Dennis's [quote](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31809962#31809962) on talk.tryitonline.net.

```
Waiting for someone to create an esolang called talk.
```

. The "Talk" language has 4 commands:

- `00` If the accumulator is 0, set the accumulator to 0.
- `01` If the accumulator is 0, set the accumulator to 1.
- `10` If the accumulator is 1, set the accumulator to 0.
- `11` If the accumulator is 1, set the accumulator to 1.

### Input:

- The input can be taken via any acceptable input method by our standard I/O rules.
- There are two inputs, the initial accumulator value and the program. You can merge these two inputs into one input or split your input into valid commands (e.g. taking them as a list; e.g. `[00, 01, 00]`) if you like.

### Output:

- On the end of a command execution, the accumulator is outputted implicitly.

### Rules:

- The input *can* be a single string or character list.
- As this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest answer, in bytes, wins.
- We take digits or strings/characters.

  ### Test cases:

```
0 0001111101 -> 1
0 000100 -> 1
0 11001000 -> 0
```

### Leaderboards

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
# Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
# Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
# Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the leaderboard snippet:

```
# [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```js
var QUESTION_ID=190819;
var OVERRIDE_USER=8478;
var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;function answersUrl(d){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+d+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(d,e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+e.join(";")+"/comments?page="+d+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(d){answers.push.apply(answers,d.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],d.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var f=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(f),answers_hash[f]=e}),d.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(d){d.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),d.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=function(){var d=String.raw`h\d`,e=String.raw`\-?\d+\.?\d*`,f=String.raw`[^\n<>]*`,g=String.raw`<s>${f}</s>|<strike>${f}</strike>|<del>${f}</del>`,h=String.raw`[^\n\d<>]*`,j=String.raw`<[^\n<>]+>`;return new RegExp(String.raw`<${d}>`+String.raw`\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?`+String.raw`(${e})`+String.raw`(?=`+String.raw`${h}`+String.raw`(?:(?:${g}|${j})${h})*`+String.raw`</${d}>`+String.raw`)`)}(),OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;function getAuthorName(d){return d.owner.display_name}function process(){var d=[];answers.forEach(function(n){var o=n.body;n.comments.forEach(function(q){OVERRIDE_REG.test(q.body)&&(o="<h1>"+q.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var p=o.match(SCORE_REG);p&&d.push({user:getAuthorName(n),size:+p[2],language:p[1],link:n.share_link})}),d.sort(function(n,o){var p=n.size,q=o.size;return p-q});var e={},f=1,g=null,h=1;d.forEach(function(n){n.size!=g&&(h=f),g=n.size,++f;var o=jQuery("#answer-template").html();o=o.replace("{{PLACE}}",h+".").replace("{{NAME}}",n.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",n.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",n.size).replace("{{LINK}}",n.link),o=jQuery(o),jQuery("#answers").append(o);var p=n.language;p=jQuery("<i>"+n.language+"</i>").text().toLowerCase(),e[p]=e[p]||{lang:n.language,user:n.user,size:n.size,link:n.link,uniq:p}});var j=[];for(var k in e)e.hasOwnProperty(k)&&j.push(e[k]);j.sort(function(n,o){return n.uniq>o.uniq?1:n.uniq<o.uniq?-1:0});for(var l=0;l<j.length;++l){var m=jQuery("#language-template").html(),k=j[l];m=m.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",k.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",k.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",k.size).replace("{{LINK}}",k.link),m=jQuery(m),jQuery("#languages").append(m)}}
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list{padding:10px;float:left}#language-list{padding:10px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/codegolf/primary.css?v=f52df912b654"> <div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">{{SIZE}}</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">{{SIZE}}</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: So there's two inputs, the sequence of commands and the initial accumulator value?

Comment: Test cases would be very helpful here.

Comment: If the accumulator condition is not met, its state remains unchanged, right?

Comment: Some test cases that don't change the accumulator, start with 1 in the accumulator or have no instructions would be good

Comment: Can _Talk_ really be considered a [programming language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2073/36398)?

Comment: @A_ That comment was probably meant as a joke. Back in the day, a language called _Lang_ would have a URL `lang.tryitonline.net` (now it's `tio.run/#lang`). So a language called _Talk_ would cause confusion with the URL for the then-recently created chatroom, which is `talk.tryitonline.net`

Comment: In the future, please refrain from changing I/O after a number of answers have been posted. I came back today and having mapped inputs allowed makes this an [entirely different challenge from what I answered](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/190826/86147).

Comment: I appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: Are we allowed to take the program as individual integers, such as `[0, 1, 1, 0]`?

Comment: @TheOnlyMrCat Yes.

Comment: @A_ does the program have to write characters 0/1 (ASCII 48/49) or can it output ASCII 0/1 (NUL or SOH)?

Comment: @osuka_ Both, as people are already using ASCII 0/1 in this challenge.

Comment: This seems kinds similar to boolfuck.

Comment: Can the accumulator be 2?

Comment: @Helena No, the accumulator can only save binary values.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
y@/
```

Input is a single list: the accumulator, followed by the pairs.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/SQf//4fZHTWsi//@P5uKMNtBRAGKDWDBlCKIMUSiQYKwOVoUgHlzKECEG5hkgqYgFAA)

#### How it works

The `y` atom performs transliteration; **[a,b]**`y`**c** replaces **a** with **b**, so it returns **b** if **a=c** and **c** if **a≠c**.

`y@/` folds/reduces the input by `y` with swapped arguments, performing one transliteration per pair.

Comment: This is the only Jelly answer that I have seen so far that only uses ASCII characters.

Comment: There were a few. [Look ma, no Unicode!](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22look+ma+no+unicode%22&filter=0)

Answer (score 23):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 43 bytes

```python
lambda s:re.sub("00|11","",s)[-1]
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3LCsIwEEX3/YohqwajTHBXyJfUImmbasA8yGMh@O8xEbF4l2fOYfwz3Z09l01cykOaeZUQh6BOMc89QXxxThghLNLxyKdOG@9CgqBKUjFdFxlVBAFjVauGiLwNW8MJZTtG/EPVaexzJXTqNhfABX1jsDhjpF0jA5eTzwm0hf3X0EGdD9qmfutbAYdfQkGIb0XLGw)

The function takes a single string as input, where the first character is the  initial state and the rest of the string represents the commands. This solution can be easily ported to other languages that have better support for regular expressions.

The difficult part is to prove the solution yields the correct outcome. To see this, we need a deep analysis of the commands. Firstly, we can see the commands have the following properties:

- **Property (1)**: commands `00` and `11` retain the accumulator state.
- **Property (2)**: commands `01` and `10` make the accumulator state the same as the second bit regardless of its original state.

Therefore, the final accumulator state is:

- **Case 1**: If no `01` or `10` command exists, the final state is the same as the initial state.
- **Case 2**: Otherwise, the last bit of the last `10` or `01` command.

Next we will show the solution yields the correct outcome in both cases. We will prove the statement for the final state `0` and the final state of `1` can be proved analogously. If the final state is `0` the input is in either of the following forms:

- `^0{2k+1}11(11|00)*`

  For **Case 1**, the input string `s` must start with `2k+1` 0s, followed by `11` and `00` commands. Eliminating `00`s and `11`s yields a single `0`, which is the final state.
- `.+10{2k+1}11(11|00)*`

  For **Case 2**, the input string ends with a `10` command, followed by zero or more `00` and `11` s. This pattern is equivalent to a `1` followed by `2k+1` 0s, and then zero or more `11`s and `00`s. Eliminating `00`s and `11`s leaves behind the last one of the `2k+1` 0s at the end of the string, which represents the final state.

Based on all the above, after eliminating `00`s and `11`s **simultaneously in one single pass** (`01001` is a counter-example if `00` is eliminated in one pass and then `11` in another pass) from the input `s`, the last character is the final state. Hence the correctness of the solution is proved.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Excellent answer, and a nice formal proof to go with it!

Comment: Thanks. I feel that people may doubt such a simple solution yields the correct outcome at the first glance. So there is a need to provide a proof for that.

Answer (score 9):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 17 bytes

```perl6
{m/.)>[(.)$0]*$/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzpXX0/TLlpDT1PFIFZLRb/2vzVXWn6RgkZOZl5qsaZCNRdnrlW6fkyKtr41F2dxYqVCXZqGikGdiqEmV@1/AwUDAwNDEDAwVNC1UzDkgogYGMB4QBkQF8w34DJUQMhAxQA)

Takes advantage of "You can merge these two inputs into one input if you like" by taking input as the accumulator value concatenated with the commands e.g. `1,[00,11]` is `10011`. If this isn't okay, than it's only 5 extra bytes to take it as [`f(accumulator, commands)`](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzpXX0/TLlpDT1PFIFZLRb82Xy26Lva/NVdafpGCRk5mXmqxpkI1F2euVbp@TIq2vjUXZ3FipUJdmoaKgY6KoSZX7X8DBQMDA0MQMDBU0LVTMOSCiBgYwHhAGRAXzDfgMlRAyEDFAA). Returns a match object that can be coerced to a string.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                }  # Anonymous code block
 m/             /   # Find the first match from the input
   .)>              # Capture a number
      [     ]*      # Followed by any number of
       (.)$0        # Pairs of identical characters
              $     # Ending the string
```

Basically this works because the `00` and `11` commands do literally nothing, while the `01` and `10` commands just set the accumulator to the second digit of the command. If there are no commands, then it takes the initial value of the accumulator instead.

Answer (score 7):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 33 bytes

The character list is passed as arguments, the initial value of the accumulator is passed as stdin.

```sh
read a
for x y;a=$[x^a?a:y]
<<<$a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYvBCsIwEETv@xUDBqqHQuKxTdX/EIWFJrQQGmhFW0u/PVqt8SDOwDLsm7l3VbDrzRhawyWYrG/RY8i5EMf@zHvOhhNprQWHiW5V7QxeTVc3JkfpyVzZoTMXpCnE/CULMR6y7YTnDEJR6RsTJN5W0XNeodhB0RfO96MI1QLUUotQkkKS4Edx@RdKegA)

---

**39 bytes**: If the commands must be a single string

Input is `accumulator` `commands` as arguments.

```sh
for x y (${(s::)2})1=$[x^$1?$1:y]
<<<$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcrBCsIwEITh@z7FgAttbrsea0TfQxQKSWihtNCItpY@ezQWD/7Hb@YVmxRKs6QwjJgwo@SljFVl9qvRI1@mG@uJtZqvZK1lTSs9m7bzGH3t0LW9P8AN5B91h@jv4EwUwGdyQ@@TQEQ0J4odlDYQQW6Dz5ZFviCkKAr82h5/IPQG)

---

For fun, here's a **50 byte** recursive one-liner ([TIO](https://tio.run/##JcxBCsIwEIXhfU7xwFkoEpjJMhY8SIm0kJQWQgtWFAw5e0zsW/18A/Pd5zKdL6l0XUeJkrkOE6gnedTuxeU7iW1pXHaoYU0estUkuWT1mZcY8AyjR1zWcIPfVHiPEXt4QWtQU1UfCsgov62hMJhZ2lhwgqgDmNF2QL014T@w@gE)):

```sh
<<<${${2+`f $[$1^${2[1]}?$1:${2[2]}] ${2:2}`}:-$1}
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 52 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,s:s and f([s[1],a][s[0]==s[1]],s[2:])or a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIVGn2KpYITEvRSFNI7o42jBWJzEWSBvE2tqCeLE6xdFGVrGa@UUKif8LijLzSjTSNJQMlHQUlAwMDAxBwMBQSVOTC1POwABTHKgaJIEkg6TCEKwTqARFH1gUpA2LKBRgswcu8x8A)

*Fixed inconsistent return type thanks to Chas Brown*

Takes input as two strings; the accumulator and the code.

Comment: Oh no, that was fast.

Comment: Nice but it has this potential problem - `f(1,'11')==f(1,'01')` is `False`; it sometimes returns an `int` and sometimes a `str`. So maybe specify it takes acc input as a string?

Comment: @ChasBrown Good call, that's much simpler than what I was thinking about.

Comment: Nice, but since your function is recursive, it cannot be anonymous. It should be [52 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIVGn2KpYITEvRSFNI7o42jBWJzEWSBvE2tqCeLE6xdFGVrGa@UUKif8LijLzSjTSNJQMlHQUlAwMDAxBwMBQSVOTC1POwABTHKgaJIEkg6TCEKwTqARFH1gUpA2LKBRgswcu8x8A "Python 3 – Try It Online").

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>11</s> 9 bytes

```
tġ₂≠ˢtt|h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3wv@TIQiDvUeeC04tKSmoy/v@PjlYyUNJRMjAwMAQBA0OlWB2EkIEBnAuUA/GBArEA)

Since it's been long enough that I've been able to forget the notion of [printing the accumulator after each command](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompkcdyx/u2vFwV2ftw60T/h9ZCBR6uHV6@qkNydXVJRl1GfYlJTUZteVA4drTC///j45WMlDSUTIwMDAEAQNDpVgdhJCBAZwLlAPxgQKxAA), I've formulated a significantly less naïve solution with some inspiration from Jo King's Perl answer.

```
       |     The output is
     tt      the last element of the last element of
t            the last element of the input
 ġ₂          split into length-2 slices
   ≠ˢ        with equal pairs removed.
       |     If there is no such element, the input
        h    's first element is the output.
```

Old solution:

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```
ġ₂ᵗc{th~h?tt|h}ˡ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3w/8hCEGfr9OTqkoy6DPuSkpqM2tML//@Pjo5WMlCK1VEyMDAwBAEDQyAPWdDAAEkAKA8SAbJjAQ)

-2 bytes from changing the input format.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 27 bytes

Takes input as `(a)(code)`, where *code* is a is list of 2-bit integers.

```javascript
a=>c=>c.map(x=>a^=x==a+1)|a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i4ZiPRyEws0KmztEuNsK2xtE7UNNWsS/yfn5xXn56Tq5eSna6RpGGhqRBskGRjoAAlDIGEIJwwMYzU1FfT1FQy58GsxMAApRACcWiDGgvQZGqDqA2ox@A8A)

---

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>47</s>  40 bytes

Takes input as `(a)(code)`, where *code* is a string.

```javascript
a=>c=>c.replace(/../g,x=>a^=x%4==a+1)&&a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcxBCoAgEIXhfaeIoFAqHaHtdJRgMItCMjKi25tCy/p5y4@30kVeH8t@tpsbTZgwEPY6Thxmt6QNk0LIubmxpwHvskOkWvGqoqDd5p01wrqZTQw4KwBApUAVnOdS5ir7RgAJpH5Q/EjqZRFBeAA)

#### How?

All possible cases are summarized below. The only two cases where we need to toggle the accumulator are \$(a=0,x=01_2)\$ and \$(a=1,x=10_2)\$.

```
  a | x (bin) | int(x) % 4 | a + 1 | equal?
----+---------+------------+-------+--------
  0 |   "00"  |  0 % 4 = 0 |   1   |   N
  1 |   "00"  |  0 % 4 = 0 |   2   |   N
  0 |   "01"  |  1 % 4 = 1 |   1   |   Y
  1 |   "01"  |  1 % 4 = 1 |   2   |   N
  0 |   "10"  | 10 % 4 = 2 |   1   |   N
  1 |   "10"  | 10 % 4 = 2 |   2   |   Y
  0 |   "11"  | 11 % 4 = 3 |   1   |   N
  1 |   "11"  | 11 % 4 = 3 |   2   |   N
```

Answer (score 4):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) -E, <s>26</s> 19 bytes

*A whopping **-7 bytes** from @Cowsquack by realizing removing all pairs works as well.*

```
s/(.)\1//g
s/.*\B//
```

Takes input concatenated together on stdin. Inspired by [Jo King's Perl answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/190830/86147).
<s>Strip trailing pairs</s> Remove all pairs, then get last digit.

<s>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1hfw8CgxtBQU0tFX5@rWF9PS0NPU0U/xlD//38DIDAEAQNDLjDbwIALKABmGHABxbj@5ReUZObnFf/XdQUA)</s>
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1hfQ08zxlBfP52rWF9PK8ZJX///fwMgMAQBA0MuMNvAgAsoAGYYcAHFuEAsw3/5BSWZ@XnF/3VdAQ)

Comment: The last line can be simply `s/.*\B//`, but anyways changing the approach slightly gives an even shorter 19 bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1hfQ08zxlBfP52rWF9PK8ZJX///fwMgMAQBA0MuMNvAgAsoAGYYcAHFuEAsw3/5BSWZ@XnF/3VdAQ "sed – Try It Online")

Comment: Huh, I didn't think that `s/(.)\1//g` would work, since it could remove the end of one pair and the start of the next, but it still works out. Excellent!

Comment: @GammaFunction `s/(.)\1//g` is equivalent to `s/00|11//g` as shown in my solution.

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>18</s> 11 bytes

```
(.)\1

!`.$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0NPM8aQi0sxQU/l/38DIDAEAQNDLjDbwIALKABmGHDhlzWEqAAA) Link includes test cases. Takes input concatenated. Saved 6 bytes thanks to @CowsQuack for pointing out that removing all doubled characters and then taking the last remaining character works, although in fact the port of @JoKing's original answer could have been golfed by 3 bytes even without that trick.

Comment: 12 bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0NPM8aQi0tPK8aJ6/9/AyAwBAEDQy4w28CACygAZhhw4Zc1hKgAAA "Retina 0.8.2 – Try It Online")

Comment: @Cowsquack D'oh, once you think about separating the stages, that's a 2-byte saving already, then another byte saved because you can use ``!`.$``, and then another 4 bytes because you don't have to limit to trailing pairs...

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 29 bytes

Defines an unnamed function on the first line with type `(Foldable t, Eq b) => b -> t [b] -> b`. For the purposes of this code golf, we can instantiate it as `Char -> [String] -> Char` where the first argument is the accumulator and the second is a list of string with each string being a single command.

```hs
foldl(#)
a#[x,y]|a==x=y|1>0=a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZvtfIS0/JyVHQ1mTK1E5ukKnMrYm0da2wrayxtDOwDbxf25iZp6CrUJKPpeCQkFRZl6JgopCmoK6gbpCtJKBgZKOgpKBIYg0RCKBIrEElAPZ2JQYwiRBZhnAFf4HAA)

Comment: Same bytecount if you define it [using prefix notation](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P902LT8nJUchjStNIVGjQqdSsybR1rbCtrLG0MbYNvF/bmJmnoKtQko@l4JCQVFmXomCikK6goFCtIaBjoGmDpA0BJKGSCRIJFZBV1fBELsWBYgeBTAPh0JDhAogZQjTBlVv8B8A). I can't believe I wrote almost the exact same answer at the same time, even including the type signature explanation…

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 38 bytes

```python
lambda l:[y for*x,y in l if[y]!=x][-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYzBDoIwAEPvfEXlMqYz2eKNZF8yd5gCsmRsC4LC1yMkaNB4aZr2tXHs6uBPUyXPkzPNpTBwuRpRhXY/sBHWw8FWatQ7OWh1FHp61taVEHmC0NobwzU0jfHFnSH0Xew7yPJhXGb97DNKk/kjQkIttMbhwyeIrfVdVi0ohZTrnk4Z4YRBpZynDCkXi4qNzolmIILQ5B86@99avIvlg28g/g2t0Qs)

Based on [Joel's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/190840/20260). Takes input as a list of the initial accumulator value (length-one string) followed by the commands (length-two strings). Finds the last command with two unequal values, and outputs its second character.

To make this fall through to the initial accumulator value when there are no such commands, we make it so that the single-char initial value string passes the test. We do so by checking if a singleton list with the last character is unequal to a list of all preceding characters, which is passed by any length-one string or length-two string with two different characters.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, <s>37</s> 33 bytes

```perl
$\=<>;s/(.)(.)/$\=$2if$\==$1/ge}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lxtbGzrpYX0NPE4j0gVwVo8w0IGWrYqifnlpb/f@/gYGBIQgYGHIZ/MsvKMnMzyv@r1uQAwA)

Input is two lines: first line is the command sequence, second is the accumulator.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
EÐḟṪṪo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/18ISHO@Y/3LkKiPL/FxsdXs51ePmxuY@a1kT@/x8drWRgYGAIAgaGSjpKBkqxOhAhAwM4FygH4qMJQFQYKsXGAgA)

-2 bytes thanks to Nick Kennedy informing me of a rules change. (His proposed golf, `EÐḟFȯṪ`, seems somewhat more clever but has the same length as my previous solution minus `s2`.) The input format now takes the commands as a list of two-character strings, but the testing footer translates from the old format for convenience.

Translated from my newer Brachylog solution.

Old version:

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
ḢẎ⁼⁹a⁸o
s2ç@ƒ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjkUPd/U9atzzqHFn4qPGHflcxUaHlzscm/T/8PJjcx81rYn8/z86WsnAwMAQBAwMlXSUDJRidSBCBgZwLlAOxIcKxAIA)

I'm not 100% sure this is correct, but it succeeds on all three test cases. Takes the commands as the left argument and the initial accumulator as the right argument.

Comment: The input is allowed to be split into a list, so you could have `EÐḟFȯṪ` with the input as e.g. `[[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[1,1],[0,1]]`.

Comment: Wow, the changes to the spec really were quite large...

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 56 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,c:f([a,1,0,a][int(c[:2],2)],c[2:])if c else a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xcq7DoAgDIXh3afoJiQdWkYSn4QwVJRo4i3q4tNjGVw843f@47mnfXOl5G6RtR8EBJPPJggyEkoM83abFLyL6GzEFJyPds6QYFyuEaQcpxaQDWNLxMTc2qb5kBBUFXVUn/9B9EPtqiqXFw)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 16 bytes

```apl
(+⌷13⍴0 1,9/⊢)/⌽
```

A tacit function which takes initial accumulator value and the program as a single integer list.

Maps the relevant sums of instruction and accumulator to an array.

Table: `(a→accumulator, i→instruction)`

```apl
a  i a+i result
00 0 0   0
01 0 1   1
10 1 11  0
11 1 12  1
```

All other cases return the same value, so they are assigned to the preexisting value of `a`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/zW0H/VsNzR@1LvFQMFQx1L/UdciTf1HPXv/pwGlH/X2PepqPrTe@FHbRKCW4CBnIBni4Rn8P03BQMEAiAwVDMHIwJALIWRgAOaAhIGkAZxvAAA)

#### Explanation

```apl
(+⌷13⍴0 1,9/⊢)/⌽ accumulator→a
              /⌽ reduce the reversed array using th following function: (reducing happens from the right)
          9/⊢)   replicate a 9 times
   13⍴0 1,       concatenate with (0,1) and expand to 13 elements → (0 1 a a a a a a a a a 0 1)
(+⌷              sum first two elements and find element at that index in the array
```

#### Solution which accepts a string

```apl
{{(13⍴0 1,9/⍺)[⍺+⍵]}/⌽(⍎¨((⍴⍵)⍴1 0)⊂('0',⍵))}
```

It was pretty ambiguous how the input was supposed to be taken, so I decided I'd leave this one in as well.

This was the original dfn, which was golfed down using Adám and Bubbler's advice.

Answer (score 3):

## Regex (JS flavor), 32 bytes

```
^(0(..)*01|1((..)*01)?)(00|11)*$
```

[Try it online!](https://regexr.com/6nmi7)

Matches if output is 1, doesn't if output is 0. Global and multiline flags enabled in link to verify multiple test cases at once, but not necessary for solution. Did I format this submission correctly?

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 111 bytes

```
def f(a,b):
    c=a
    for i in range(0,len(b)-1,2):
        c=(not b[i])*(c or b[i] or b[i+1]) or c*b[i]*b[i+1]
    return c
```

Ungolfed. EDIT: AHHH Someone beat me to it!

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-ir`, 16 bytes

```
"(!;½|':"=['_"|_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//9fSUPR@tDeGnUrJdto9Xilmvj//w0MDQ0MgMjgv25mEQA)

### Explained:

1. Takes the implicit input and right shifts the accumulators value to the bottom
2. Repeat the following (length of stack - 1 divided by 2) times

2.1. Shift the accumulator back to the top

2.2. Compare for equality with the first part of the command

2.2.1. If true, replace the accumulator, otherwise pop the replacement

Input is taken as the initial acc value concatenated with the source. E.g.

```
010011000
```

- First char is acc value
- Rest is program

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 36 bytes

```hs
f(x:y:s)=f s.last.(:[y|x/=y])
f _=id
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02jwqrSqljTNk2hWC8nsbhET8MqurKmQt@2MlaTK00h3jYz5X9uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCikKagpKBgYEhCBgYKimoG6j/BwA)

Takes input as `f(string)(char)` where the character is the accumulator and the string is the list of commands.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
ø`:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8I4Eq///o6MNdAxidRSAlCGIMkSh4IJYlED1geRiuQwA)

Zip, dump on the stack, replace.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 3 bytes

```
F|t
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=F%7Ct&i=%220%22+[%2200%22+%2201%22+%2211%22+%2211%22+%2201%22]%0A%220%22+[%2200%22+%2201%22+%2200%22]%0A%220%22+[%2211%22+%2200%22+%2210%22+%2200%22]%0A&a=1&m=2)

For each instruction, perform character translation.

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 8 bytes

```
{{)er}/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1fWPe/uloztahWv/Z/3X8lAyWFaCUDIKlkYAgkDOEEkBsLAA)

Takes input on the stack in the form of `"0" ["00" "01" "11" "11" "01"]`. Does string replacement using every command.

Answer (score 2):

## [Headass](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Headass), 22 bytes

```
U[{N-()]PNE:U(])U[:U;}
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIixudWxsLCJVW3tOLSgpXVBORTpVKF0pVVs6VTt9IiwiIiwiMFxuMFxuMFxuMFxuMVxuMVxuMVxuMVxuMVxuMFxuMSIsIiJd)

```
U[{N-()]PNE:U(])U[:U;} full program

U[                     save initial state of accumulator to storage register
  {        :         } while
   N-()                input remains
            U(])    ;    if input == accumulator state
                U[         set accumulator to next input
                  :      else
                   U       discard next input
       ]P              print final state of accumulator
         NE            go to code block 1
                       block does not exist, exits with error
```

There is room for golfing maybe if I can avoid storing anything in the comparison register (i.e. having it remain 0 for the entirety of the program and never using `(`), but it might not be possible.

Answer (score 2):

## Regex (any flavor), 15 bytes

```
(^|0)1(00|11)*$
```

[Try it on regex101!](https://regex101.com/r/ySrh84/1)

It was pointed out before that the problem can be simplified:

- `00` and `11` are no-ops. `01` unconditionally sets the value to 1 while `10` sets to 0.
- The output is 1 if and only if the input is 1 and the entire code is no-op or the last non-no-op command is `01`.

The regex precisely does the job: `(00|11)*$` after discarding no-ops at the end, the last thing found is `(^|0)1` the input 1 or a `01` command.

`1(00|11)*$` does not work because the 1 may be part of another no-op command `11`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>58</s> 40 bytes

Add one byte for a full program: change `f` to `$0`.

```bash
(($1=$2-a?a:$3,1))&&f $1 ${@:4}||echo $1
```

<s>[58 bytes](https://tio.run/##VcxBCsIwEIXh/ZzigYEqUpjpMiIeRJRGO6WF0oIVXZScPWYsLnyrP99AbmHuUrvdLSkc3VLt6xbu7OSa27OXeHLirSX3BVZVrCPpvZvyK/jSSUyR3l0/KB4aGgz9qAc0E@krDJj1ibKEM6X8t8BV1EyjJgYzi40FGwitwAzbCvlmwl/gDEWB3wzkH4Q@)</s>
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYtRC4JAEITf91cMdKgHCW71ZFj@lStXFA4PMupB/e2Xkl0P0Qwsu/vNXEzf@DrRg08SxYXapeZscrXfstZRVEMx1FDmh2kc5dq4@fYTPZvWCm5iKti2kyMqR/IwFr3ckaZQy5fmckmV68RneJuDl32D4gSmL1zmRwHyCniNBZgRI47xo9D8CzN6AQ)

The ternary will return false when `$1` is set to `0`, but the `,1` at the end ensures the whole `((expression))` will return true, *except* a syntax error.

When all the arguments are consumed, a syntax error happens and the recursion ends.

---

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 16 bytes

```
Ｆ⪪η²Ｆ⁼θ§ι⁰≔§ι¹θθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBI7ggJ7NEI0NHwUhTUwEs4lpYmphTrFGoo@BY4pmXklqhkamjYKAJlHYsLs5Mz9NAEjbU1FEo1LTmCijKzCvRALL@/zdQMDAwMAQBA8P/umU5AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes separate arguments. Explanation:

```
Ｆ⪪η²
```

Split the instructions into pairs of digits and loop over them.

```
Ｆ⁼θ§ι⁰
```

If the accumulator is equal to the first digit...

```
≔§ι¹θ
```

... then assign the second digit to it.

```
θ
```

Print the accumulator at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
!dh2Ol4$Ys0)
```

Takes the input as a 2-column matrix where each row is a command, and a number

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/XzElw8g/x0QlsthA8///aAMFA2sFAwVDawVDOAHkxnIZAAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8F8xJcPIP8dEJbLYQPO/S8j/aAMFA2sFAwVDawVDOAHkxnIZcCHJAVlgEai0AUihAVTYEAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
fØ½Ḃ⁹;Ṫ
```

A dyadic Link accepting the program as a list of integers on the left and the initial accumulator on the right which yields an integer.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9qZWxsef//ZsOYwr3huILigbk74bmq////WzMsMCwyLDBd/zA)** Or see a [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/t8IxDex/uaHrUuNP64c5V/w8vd9B/1LTm///oaAMdIDLUMQZCw9hYLh2YgAGMY6xjoGME5RrqRMOEYXwDhEoDhCqgcQj9xjBRIx0jGNMQwTQCWxwLAA)

Comment: I am removing input-mapping because @GammaFunction recommended me to do this.

Comment: @A_ ah OK cant delete on mobile so will have to address this later

Comment: @A_ fixed up to work with 0,1,2,3 the unmapped version of the instructions as digits is that OK?

Comment: Yes, that's OK.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>45</s> 41 bytes

```c
f(a,i)char*i;{a=*i?f(a^*i?a:i[1],i+2):a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1EnUzM5I7FIK9O6OtFWK9MeKBQHpBKtMqMNY3UytY00rRKta/9n5pUo5CZm5mloKlRzcRYUAflpGkqqyTF5SjoKaRrqBuo6CkoGBgaGIGBgqKSpaY1XmYEBXiVAM0BqIIpq/wMA)

4 bytes shaved off thanks to @ErikF!

Comment: You can save 4 bytes by using the usual trick of storing the return value in the first parameter: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1EnUzM5I7FIK9O6OtFWK9MeKBQHpBKtMqMNY3UytY00rRKta/9n5pUo5CZm5mloKlRzcRYUAflpGkqqyTF5SjoKaRrqBuo6CkoGBgaGIGBgqKSpaY1XmYEBXiVAM0BqIIpq/wMA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: I don't see how this fulfils "On the end of a command execution, the accumulator is outputted implicitly". You have outsourced that part to the caller, so you should then count the caller too.

Comment: @Lundin: it also says the [standard I/O rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods), and those mention that functions may output via return value. Also, most answers here do this.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Ok well there's another function solution including the printing put they aren't really comparable this way. Either way, a parameter is _not_ a function's return value in C.

Comment: @Lundin: It's a standard code golf trick: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106067/46301. At code golf we don't care about standards conformance; if TIO runs it it's valid :)

Comment: In this case it's rather about re-defining the language to some local standard only used on this site. But it is what it is.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 38 bytes

```php
<?=strtr($argn,['00'=>'',11=>''])[-1];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62uKSopEhDJbEoPU8nWt3AQN3WTl1dx9AQRMVqRusaxlr//28ABIYgYGD4L7@gJDM/r/i/rhsA)

Basically port of [Jo King's idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/190830/81663).

Answer (score 1):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 28 bytes

```
/~@/i~/i<
/=?/~iR:l}i{l1-=?!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/1@/zkE/s04/04ZL39Zevy4zyCqnNrM6x1DX1l7x/38DBUMgNFAwgJIGAA)

Takes input as a series of space separated bytes (Runic does not understand lists). The first byte is the initial state and every other byte is the program. No validation is performed (i.e. it assumes only valid programs are given as input and it doesn't care what value is used to represent `0` and `1`).

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 33 bytes

```ruby
->a,s{s[/(00|11)*$/]="";s[-1]||a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYyxCoQwEER/JQQL74hx1la8H1m2iIWdIBeFHK7fnkvEaWbeK@Z7zL@8TLn7BBfPyH0LKNHr3fQyWTtG7khUw5W3Y4@GLQwAqgFZ9yBwz@LqrkDmcaXEr2E7NenCiSEu8eB9uZUr/wE)

Answer (score 1):

## x86 Assembly, 33 Bytes

Takes the initial accumulator state in `CL` (integer `0` or `1`) and the address of the commands as a zero-terminated ASCII String in `ESI`. Leaves the final accumulator state in `CL`.

Point the call instruction at offset `0x1B` (label `interpret` in the Explanation).

```
3C 30 74 03 B0 01 C3 30 C0 C3 E8 F1 FF FF FF 38
C8 AC 75 07 E8 E7 FF FF FF 88 C1 AC 84 C0 75 EA
C3
```

**Explanation** (Using Intel Syntax):

```
; function to convert ASCII '1'/'0' into 0 or 1 int values (from AL to AL)
ctob:
        CMP AL, 0x30 ; '0'
        JE .zero
        MOV AL, 1
        RET
        .zero:
        XOR AL, AL
        RET

; interpreting function
        interp_lp:
                CALL ctob     ; convert to number
                CMP AL, CL    ; compare to current accumulator
                LODSB         ; read the next character of the string
                              ; this doesn't affect any flags and we need to do
                              ; it in both cases anyway
                JNE interpret ; if AL != CL (from above, not the new value of AL), skip forward
                CALL ctob     ; convert AL to number
                MOV CL, AL    ; store AL in CL
interpret:      LODSB         ; read the next character of the string
                TEST AL, AL   ; check if it is a zero byte
                JNZ interp_lp ; if not, jump back into the loop
        RET
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 9 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
1∊11+\⍤|⌽
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=M3zU0WVoqB3zqHdJzaOevQA&f=S1MwUDAAIkMFQzAyMORKgwsZGIA5IGEgaQDngyiIGFwNjAMA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

Input format is the same as [Razetime's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210521/78410).

```
1∊11+\⍤|⌽
        ⌽  Reverse the input list
  11   |    Modulo 11 (change 11 to 0)
            Now the program outputs 1 iff the list starts with 0 0 ... 0 1
    +\⍤     Cumulative sum
1∊          Test if it contains a 1
```

The proof of the statement

> a list starts with 0 0 ... 0 1 <=> its cumulative sum contains 1

is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>68</s> 62 bytes

```c
t(s,e,a)char*s,*e;{for(;s<e;++s)a=*s++-48^a?a:*s-48;puts(&a);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxNCsIwFIT3PcUDQfJXScVFMVUPUio8YmwDNUqSuik9e0yhwiy@mWFGl3pE16cUSRBGINUDehYEM2p@vj1RoTGK80DxwgLn5am@4w3PLGRSnykGskeqlrSzTo/Tw0AToreuPwzXwroIL7SOrIC@1wLWd2Asmy@FuQCIZOX22AnYgOeD0bh/Trei6lrZQQmnmqq88yZO3oFUxZKSTFUlZZb8AQ)

Takes a pointer to the start of the source string, a pointer to the end of the source string (start + strlen(start)), and the initial accumulator value.

Old version (prints ASCII 48/49 for 0/1):

```c
t(s,e,a)char*s,*e;{for(;s<e;++s)a=*s++-48^a?a:*s-48;putchar(a+48);}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Crystal](https://crystal-lang.org/), 46 bytes

With commands in an `Array(Tuple(Int32,Int32))`, such as `[{0,0}, {0,1}, {0,0}]`.

`def f(s,i);i.map{|c,v|s+=~(s^c)&(s^v)%2};s;end`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy6qLC5JzPn/PyU1TSFNo1gnU9M6Uy83saC6JlmnrKZY27ZOozguWVMNSJZpqhrVWhdbp@alcHEVKCqkKRjoKERXG@gY1OoASUM4aQhnxyooKxRn5JfmpCikFpYm5igY4tRogF@xIVwZyHwDXFoM/v8HAA)

It's pretty simple to understand in a more readable form:

```
def f(state, instructions)
  instructions.map do |check, value|
    state += ~(state ^ check) & (state ^ value) % 2
  end
  state
end
```

The function loops through each command, automatically unpacking the tuple values into `c` and `v`. It then sets the `state` by the formula

```
state = state + NOT(state XOR check) AND (state XOR value) mod 2
```

which I arrived at mostly by trial and error. Once all commands have been processed, it returns the state value.

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 38 bytes

```java
a->p->p.reduce(a,(s,c)->c<1|c>2?s:c%2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLLTsMwELz3K1aRItkotewe@wjiAuKAOMCt9GAcp3LJw/I6SBX024vjhIKURoninZ3MTsY@yE85PxQfZ1Pb1nk4hJp13lTsZjWbYGXXKG/a5moTvdOy7lsz271XRoGqJCI8SdPA1wxgRNFLH16frSmgDj3y4p1p9tsdSLdHGqkAj42/H6etX9v/VVi/xFF5DuXmLOe5DTdzuuiUJjIjmCk6z9VafKt8cYtLlS7oeRVVn98PWvntLgzzGj3CZhwH8AU8g4TzBE7ZBRJTKLLElCUmLDHVElMtMdUSUy3Ouegvfr3Fr@lG/K9xGiIoW0d@Y4ghLIco6CUJ03iQSoVsSMha77WjPWPLd6uRMewYqLbQPWsoB5K4kHoZp7GrfOCUTFpbHUnQpcPyDoM4uXNOHnE8O6QXZGgr40lCbtebt7cHxmhCKauljaeAIMxzGG0xKx3qiGawoJRe/B3R65q1nWc2WPMlSdICUlxCWqRNkvW/l0X72Whx/PQ065/T@Qc)

The inputs are an `int` and an `IntStream` of `0`, `1`, `2` or `3`, which correspond to `00`, `01`, `10`, `11` from binary.