# Simplify the following C ascii graphing function

Tags: ascii-art, tips, c

This wasn't originally intended for code-golf, just as a little debugging routine to roughly visualize something "goofy" going on in a model of some (irrelevant here) physical process. But when I saw how surprisingly short it was, compared to my expectations, I just wondered if it can be further shortened. And that's primarily with respect to #statements (rather than #chars just by shortening variable names).

So, the function's `void asciigraph ( double *f, int n )` where `f[]` contains `n` doubles representing values of some more-or-less continuous function to be illustrated/graphed on your terminal. My implementation is below, along with a test driver, whose output is below that. Can you do better/shorter?...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
/* --- entry point --- */
void asciigraph ( double *f, int n ) {
  int    row=0,nrows=24, col=0,ncols=78;
  double bigf=0.0;
  for ( col=0; col<n; col++ )
    if ( fabs(f[col]) > bigf ) bigf = fabs(f[col]);
  for ( row=0; row<nrows; row++ ) {
    double yval = bigf*((double)(nrows/2-row))/((double)(nrows/2));
    for ( col=0; col<ncols; col++ )
      printf("%c",(yval*f[(col*(n-1))/(ncols-1)]>=yval*yval? '*':' '));
    printf("\n"); }
  } /* --- end-of-function asciigraph() --- */

#ifdef TESTDRIVE
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  double f[999], pi=3.14159;        /* stored function to be graphed */
  int    i=0, N=511;            /* f[] index */
  void   asciigraph();
  for ( i=0; i<N; i++ ) {
    double x = 2.0*pi*((double)i)/((double)(N-1));
    f[i] = .5*sin(2.*x+pi/3.) + 1.*sin(1.*x+pi/2.); }
  asciigraph(f,N);
  } /* --- end-of-function main() --- */
#endif
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLRjpswEHzPV6xSVTEOMYG76C4lpH@QH6A8EIPJSsRGQNJUVX69dO3jGk5XHrzLeD073rFcVVIOX1DL@lKUsOv6Ao047WcP6Jz3J0KGq8EC8k4iVm3enIBBYS7HugSufEDdgwYPfs/A5fS15mey9jWFLomefZCmtv8UuuTlNabC8fwRK5WsxdpCyrRE7EpjG3baheUSvJklRUXbKj92TKWEZx7s3Xlq7ULyYfPB6MTENuycIpdaVqf4n5Rf17wmDkvFGXsDPeZOBNGKgucFn3DP9fmfdnvXj/oBmpbmo9j8q5z7zPbjKmVUwplehZbenaI02ydu2y7fYcEX3xaweO/1zvJDz70Y7oTdBzv3c46aRNg0bytJUz/lLXDKr2k23na8q0q3223mQ4PJkwifw802tswBh643bVmAumjZo9HQGziW4FwnmAcPj5EchUOyCcMYJh9xKGqHuihvb/Xu8cDk@bCJOWgHhrsDLZ8tuZEfkVjzBh@O4NSFgx3b6ECKGZWLDe9Qs0jw27LB4El4sIRQODAcwUiMc5tIUv7BEd2HP1LVedUNq/r8Fw)

Compile it (for linux) as `cc -DTESTDRIVE asciigraph.c -lm -o asciigraph` and then the sample output is

```
******                                                                      **
********                                                                  ****
*********                                                                *****
**********                                                              ******
***********                                                            *******
************                                                          ********
*************                                                        *********
*************                                                       **********
**************                                                     ***********
***************                                                   ************
****************                                                 *************
******************************************************************************
                  *********************************************               
                  *******************************************                 
                   *****************************************                  
                    *********************          *****                      
                     *****************                                        
                       ************                                           
                         ********
```

So, the eleven lines comprising asciigraph() above can be reduced two ways: **(a)** just "syntactically compressing" the code (e.g., put the final `}` on the same line as the final statement), or **(b)** by finding a niftier algorithm than mine, which compares each f-value to the yval "level line" (in which case maybe your algorithm wouldn't need to find that bigf at all). Obviously (I'd think it's obvious), the "niftier algorithm" approach is what I'm more interested in.

Replacing the test driver with the following will yield a moving wave:

```
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  double f[999], pi=3.14159;            /* stored function to be graphed */
  double t=0.0, dt=0.05, w1=16.,w2=3.;  int Nt=50;
  int    i=0, N=511;                    /* f[] index */
  void   asciigraph();
  while ( --Nt > 0 ) {
    for ( i=0; i<N; i++ ) {
      double x = 2.0*pi*((double)i)/((double)(N-1));
      f[i] = .75*sin(2.*x+pi/3.+w1*t) + 1.*sin(1.*x+pi/2.+w2*t); }
    system("sleep 0.25; clear");
    asciigraph(f,N);
    t += dt; }
  } /* --- end-of-function main() --- */
```

Comment: No, it has to be \$2\$ passes either way.

Comment: A quick start would be removing whitespace, comments and shortening variable names. Have you had a look at the [Tips for golfing in C](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2203/tips-for-golfing-in-c?r=SearchResults) page?

Comment: I've added a TIO link to make it easier to test and modify your code. My understanding is that only the _asciigraph()_ function needs to be golfed, so I've put the other parts in the _Header_ and _Footer_ sections. But feel free to edit if that's not what you meant.

Comment: Would this be a better [code-golf] question than a C tips question?

Comment: "This wasn't originally intended for code-golf..." Hm... does that mean it should be tagged as "code-golf"? You do say you are more interested in a more clever algorithm, but it seems to be stated more as a preference than a straight-up requirement.

Comment: Just FYI, we have the [atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf) tag to focus on the number of statements. **But** be aware that 1) it is _much_ harder to specify correctly and 2) I don't think it would be interesting in that particular case.

Comment: BTW is the `yval` calculation correct? `yval = bigf*((double)(nrows/2-row))/((double)(nrows/2))` is functionally equivalent to `yval = bigf * (nrows / 2 - row) / (nrows / 2)`, since you do the integer calculations and *then* convert the result to double, after it has already been truncated.

Comment: I think this should be changed to a codegolf challenge and opened to all languages. Is there interest in doing so? Otherwise it would be good to have a separate challenge.

Comment: @Arnauld Thanks for the TIO link edited into the post. Very cute! And please see both additional Edits (especially the second one) at the bottom, which I made in response to yours. Thanks again.

Comment: @gastropner Re `yval`, `nrows/2` is meant to be truncated (although in this case, 24/2=12 isn't). That simply tells us which row represents the x-axis. The "outer division" has to be float. Note: in C, I always explicitly and very carefully cast everything in a mixed mode expression. And I can pretty much guarantee you that if you don't, then you'll sooner-or-later (and much more likely sooner) shoot yourself in the foot (or maybe an even more painful place:)

Comment: I've put a sandbox post at https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18310/42248 with a suggested modified version of this for a [tag:code-golf] challenge that's open to all languages. Modifications include display of x-axis and scaling to y-range (without assuming symmetric about x-axis). I've acknowledged the inspiration of this question.

Comment: TIO does not work like a console so ansii escape codes will not work, TIO's output is the raw output.  You will not be able to get animations or anything.  I'm not sure if you figured this out, but if you want a new link for TIO you can hit the chain button at the top.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>164 167</s> 162 bytes

```c
r,c;void asciigraph(f,n,b,y)double*f,b,y;{for(b=0,r=n;r--;)b=fmax(b,fabs(f[r]));for(;++r<24;puts(""))for(y=b-b/12*r,c=0;c<78;)putchar("* "[y*f[c++*~-n/77]<y*y]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVHbbqswEHzPV6zSF9vcAm2URoZ@Qn4A8WAbnKyUGGRIFVSln166kJ6ec/bBWo/GszNrEx2NmZ7QmfO1biDvhxrb@PS2@gtd1HAiZPKhke8t1qB6g3j0qjsxG7pQhyOv26s@N8LOF/lhW890sQl94aSPIsl1YS/qxnRole6ZLX3FuZxZMgh8nr3I7jr0bL3mfAbHQkc6STNBE4uNNPnuVXJimJPybC1gXY7CliYIxGfkkt2uykcxVlzeJ3QDXBQ6YDC3yh9NCPMzENS/lxVw@FgBPOyCLff7fRVCh8VznL6k270EqkRAP7S@qcFenRmwdTC0oBtYMhMsEtKYB1Ah5YRDsU3T5e2fIg1L49DVze3BX1YH/y6PS4Ip8OyWcgLmBzqC4Mfkr80bFJDFG9GhYOyBceTJb88OUcoXMZIrsSJ6vBU9OpbF4hZ0mDzHHAJI4wVMf8As5hLuK/j/Pw@L0H36Mvasjv0UnS/f)

Thanks to @Arnauld for -4 and @JohnForkosh for the bugfix.

Slightly golfed less

```c
r,c;
void asciigraph(f,n,b,y)double*f,b,y;{
  for(b=0,r=n;r--;)
    b=fmax(b,fabs(f[r]));
  for(;++r<24;puts(""))
    for(y=b-b/12*r,c=0;c<78;)
      putchar("* "[y*f[c++*~-n/77]<y*y]);
}
```