# Find the number of integers in the range from 1 to N that ends with 2

Tags: code-golf, math

## Task

As input you have:

- a positive integer `N`

And you should output:

- The number of integers in \$[1,N]\$ (an inclusive range) which end with the digit \$2\$ in base ten.

## Test cases

```
1 -> 0
2 -> 1
5 -> 1
10 -> 1
12 -> 2
20 -> 2
30 -> 3
54 -> 6
97 -> 10
100 -> 10
```

## Rules

It is a code-golf so the lowest score in bytes wins!

Comment: [This looks neat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BR4a1.png) [as a series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vy2bq.png) [of graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub17h.png).

Comment: Chameleon? (filler)

Answer (score 20):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 17 bytes

```python
lambda n:(n+8)/10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPSiNP20JT39Dgf1p@kUKmQmaeQlFiXnqqhrGpphWXgkJBUWZeiUKmjkKaRqbmfwA) Uses Python 2's integer division. In Python 3 would be a byte longer with `lambda n:(n+8)//10`.

Comment: How'd you come up with this?

Comment: @S.S.Anne I noticed the result increases by one every 10 integers, so integer division by 10 was necessary. Then it was just a matter of finding the correct offset so that `f(1)=0, f(2)=1`

Comment: My first crack at it was `lambda n:n/10+(n%10>1)`

Comment: @Cruncher still a really nice try :D

Comment: Well done. My usual code golf experience is to formulate my answer and then look what the geniuses of code-golf-mastery have come up with and then stare aghast at my overall ineptitude. But today I got the same answer. It's the small wins in life.

Comment: @BellyBuster I thank you for your compliment. I wouldn't call myself a genius of code-golf-mastery... But even the both of us can come up with some really nice golfs every now and then :)

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ḋm⁵L
```

A monadic Link accepting a positive integer, `N`, which yields a non-negative integer.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjq7cR41bff7//29oZAQA)**

#### How?

Every tenth number starting with \$2\$ ends with the digit \$2\$...

```
Ḋm⁵L - Link: integer, N                           e.g. 15
Ḋ    - dequeue (implicit range [1..N]) -> [2..N]       [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
  ⁵  - literal ten                                     10
 m   - modulo slice                                    [2,12]
   L - length                                          2
```

---

[Alternative 4 byter](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/bwupR49b///8bGhkBAA):

```
+8:⁵
```

Add eight, integer divide by ten (as first used in [RGS's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200364/53748) I believe).

Comment: Interesting method. Looks like the "add 8 then int-divide by 10" that everyone is doing is the same length: `+8:⁵`([TIO](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/bwupR49b///8bGhkBAA "Jelly – Try It Online"))

Comment: "as first used in RGS's Python answer I believe" :') also, I should really learn my Jelly atoms... 4 bytes is a really nice length :D

Answer (score 7):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pl`, <s>13</s> 10  bytes

*@Grimmy got it back down to 10 bytes, with correct output.*

```perl
$_+=1<chop
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXtvW0CY5I7/g/38To3/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA)

Comment: doesn't return 0 for 1

Comment: Isn't an empty string a form of 0? :)   I've fixed it.

Comment: 10 bytes: [`$_+=1<chop`](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXtvW0CY5I7/g/38To3/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA). Properly outputs `0` for input `1` ([relevant meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8400/6484)).

Comment: @Grimmy nice fix, i had [11 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19DJV7b1kJT39bQ4P9/w3/5BSWZ@XnF/3UL/uv6ZuaVpKanFgEA) but using -Minteger

Comment: This requires that the input has no trailing newline? Like the one you'd get if you run `perl -pe '$_+=1<chop'` and input a number..?

Comment: @ilkkachu That is correct.  Or, you can add a `-l` flag to the command line, as I have now done.

Comment: @Xcali, oo, I didn't remember `-l` chomps the newline on input too, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <strike>8</strike> 7 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)

Full program

```apl
⌊.1×8+⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc5BCsIwFEXRebYiFt9L1bqcQsFJwUy7AkXEmbggd5KNxH8zeJNwzydzWffLNq@3a6uPe2n19Rz0@067@v7w0ko6pJIUcyzHxtgxdoqdY1PsQtNDSpGKVsSiFrnoBRDCCPfbCCOMMMIII4wwIiMyIvfvIPL4Bw)

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##Hc5BCsIwFEXRebYiFt9L1bqcQsFJwUy7AkXEmbggd5KNxH8zeJNwzydzWffLNq@3a6uPe2n19Rz0@067@v7w0ko6pJIUcyzHxtgxdoqdY1PsQtNDSpGKVsSiFrnoBRDCCPfbCCOMMMIII4wwIiMyIvfvIPL4Bw) using `.1×`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>7</s> <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
R%⁵ċ2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z9I9VHj1iPdRv///zcyAgA) Thanks to Nick Kennedy for saving me one byte.

How it works:

```
R      Range from 1 to n,
 %⁵    modulo 10.
   ċ2  Then count how many of those are 2.
```

Comment: `R%⁵ċ2` saves 1

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>15</s> 13 bytes

```
.+
$*
.{2,10}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRYtLr9pIx9Cg9v9/EyMA) Edit: Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Grimmy. Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
.{2,10}
```

Count the number of multiples of 10, each of which contains an integer that ends in 2 in base 10, plus count an additional match for a final 2-9, as that's enough for one last integer that ends in 2 in base 10.

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, 14 Bytes

```
f x=div(x+8)10
```

Comment: you can replace `floor` and `/` with `div`.

Comment: The point-free version `(\`div\`10).(+8)` scores the same.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
8+T÷
```

Same approach as everyone else.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fQjvk8Pb//41MAQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/X@xydXPXknhUdskBSV7v/8W2iGHt//X@Q8A).

Some (slightly) more interesting 5-[bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) alternatives:

```
LT%2¢
L€θ2¢
L2Å¿O
FNθΘO
```

[Try each online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/X@xydXPXknhUdskBSX7/35KPiGqRocWWQE5EJa9kjWQzQWUeNS05twOmByMg5A2Otx6aL8/WBLChEu5@Z3bcW4GWArK/F@r8x8A)

**Explanation:**

```python
8+     # Add 8 to the (implicit) input-integer
  T÷   # Integer-divide it by 10
       # (after which the result is output implicitly)

L      # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-integer]
 T%    # Take modulo-10 on each
       # or
 €θ    # Leave the last digit of each
   2¢  # Count the amount of 2s
       # (after which the result is output implicitly)

L      # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-integer]
 2Å¿   # Check for each whether it ends with a 2 (I'm actually surprised it vectorizes..)
    O  # Sum to get the amount of truthy values

F      # Loop `N` in the range [0, (implicit) input-integer):
 N     #  Push `N`
  θ    #  Pop and leave only its last digit
   Θ   #  05AB1E trutify: check if it's exactly 1
    O  #  Sum all values on the stack together
       # (after the loop, the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: I like the fact that you are "trutifying" in your last explanation. Almost like "making look like a trout"!

Comment: another four byte solution: `<T/î`

Answer (score 4):

### Python 3, <strike>55</strike> 40 bytes

Any help with golfing it would be appreciated

```
lambda N:sum(x%10==2for x in range(N+1))
```

Lots of thanks to the commentors for helping me out( I have problems with memory, see names below)

Comment: can you help me then?

Comment: See the upper answer.

Comment: My best advice, for this challenge and in general, is to think about the problem and try to figure out a way to compute the result directly instead of iterating through all the numbers, etc. Iteration is slow, and sometimes it's the only solution - but very often there's A Better Way that you can find if you put some thought into it.

Comment: Welcome! Please see https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python for golfing in Python, and observe patterns in other questions that might help you get an idea on the practices in code golfing. Note the objective is not just to solve the problem at hand (in fact, generally we borrow solutions already posted and port into other languages) but also to implement the solution as efficiently as possible.

Comment: If you wish to solve it this way, with iteration, you may be best off using list-comprehension and check the len, it's definitely not the best way to approach it. Also, it's often best to express it as a lambda function to save chars. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUcHPKic1TyO6QiEtv0ihQiEzT6EoMS89VcNP21AzM02huKRIo0IzWtcw1tZWyUgpVvM/SF0mQp2xqaYVl0JBUWZeiUaaUnVmrYKunUJ1mkamZq2S5n8A "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Can you please format your answer correctly? There appears to be an extra four spaces of indentation as well as a newline

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: lambda N:sum(x%10==2for x in range(N+1))

Answer (score 4):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator)

I know I'm 7 months late but this is my first code golf answer. I'm looking for some easier coding challenges to take down. I have two answers(one where I tried it without looking at any answers, then one after I looked through some answers.).

### First Answer, 62 bytes:

`f(N)=\sum_{n=1}^N\left\{\operatorname{mod}(n,10)=2:1,0\right\}`

[image]

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zikegfft1e)

Explanation:

```
f(N)=                                               a function taking in an argument of N
     \sum_{n=1}^N                                   summation from 1 to N
                 \left\{                            starting piecewise
                        \operatorname{mod}(n,10)=2: if the remainder of n/10 is 2...
1                                                   sum 1
 ,                                                  otherwise...
  0                                                 sum 0
   \right\}                                         end piecewise
```

Not too sure why I can't take out the `\left` and `\right` for the brackets(`{` and `}`). Theoretically it should work(I've taken out the `\left`'s and `\right`'s of all the other "left-right pairs"), but I guess Desmos doesn't allow it.

### Second Answer, <strike>20</strike> 18 bytes:

Saved two bytes thanks to [@golf69](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/94333/golf69)

`f(N)=floor(.1N+.8)`

[image]

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vozzazyef6)

Explanation:

My answer is equivalent to `f(N)=floor((N+8)/10)`, which is explained in [RGS's comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/200363/find-the-number-of-integers-in-the-range-from-1-to-n-that-ends-with-2?page=1&tab=oldest#comment476894_200364) under his answer.

Comment: 18 bytes: `f(N)=floor(.1N+.8)`

Comment: @golf69 Thanks! I can't believe I didn't think to distribute the fraction...

Answer (score 3):

## [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/A-ee/w/wiki/Code-Page)

```
8+T/
```

Just another boring formula: Add eight, divide by 10. (W performs integer division if both operands are integers.)

## [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w) `d`, 5 [bytes](https://github.com/A-ee/w/wiki/Code-Page)

```
[ⁿNy|
```

Uncompressed:

```
Tm2=Wk
```

### Explanation

```
    W % For every number in the range [1 .. N]:
      % Keep all that satisfies:
Tm    % After modulo by 10,
  2=  % The result is equal to 2
     k% Find the length of that
```

Comment: `2=` is a really frequent operation, I need to make a built-in for that. :D `Wk` = `K` too...

Answer (score 3):

## Powershell, <del>50</del> 20 bytes

```
1.."$args"-match"2$"
```

$args are arguments to pass as number.

Comment: I think that means you can omit the `1..50` and then your score would be 10 or 11.

Comment: @S.SAnne how to omit that? Please help I am new to code golfing.

Comment: `$args` is an array of arguments [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/31BPT0klsSi9WEk3N7EkOUPJSEXp////pgYA "PowerShell – Try It Online"). See [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables)

Comment: Thanks I knew it but didn't thought I can use it here.

Comment: Your objective is to make your byte count lower. Remove `1.."$args"-` and then put something in the header to make it work.

Comment: You need to actually output the count. [Simple Fix for +8 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X8NQT09JJbEovVhJNzexJDlDyUhFSVMvOb80r@T///@GBgYA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 12 bytes

```julia
x->(x+8)÷10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPifZvu/QtdOo0LbQvPwdkOD/wVFmXklOXkaaRqGmppcCJ4RCs8UhWdogMoFqv0PAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 25 bytes

```
{(1..it).count{it%10==2}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYyxCsMwDAX3fMVbCtJQ42QMuJ0L/QmTxCCayiUoWYy/3fUtd9N9su2i7Yo70gx6qTHuD3QjtEKjc2LslnyqFbHb6EOYam3pVHyjKDHKgM7vEDVKdGxxfYtuxE9nuW96zJ55qGiT/wM)

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt) <sup>[sic!]</sup>, 3 bytes

Finally found the right language. I had a now-deleted answer in Vim, but it returned the empty string for an input of 1 :(

```
8+₀
```

Explanation:

```
8    In fact, I have no idea whether is this language stack-based, I guess it pushes 8
 +   add that 8 to the seemingly-implicit input
  ₀  divide by 10. There are also instructions to divide by numbers from 2 to 11 :)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f/fQvtRU8P//0YA)

Comment: Pyt? Maybe Pyth...

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
#ȯ=2→dḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X/nEelujR22TUh7uWPz//39DAwMA)

Comment: Nice - but there's an even golfier way...

Comment: [5 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7///B2QwNti////xsaGAAA). EDIT: Ah @DominicvanEssen already mentioned there is a shorter way, most likely referring to this.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen It was too boring to implement.

Comment: Haha I kind-of agree...  but did it anyway!

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to Jo King*

```
hs+8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P6NY2@L///@GBgYA) or [check all test cases](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8X9GsbbF////ow11jHRMdQwNdAyNdIwMdIwNdExNdCzNgSIGsQA)

**How?**

```
            # implicit input
    +8      # plus 8            
   s        # convert to string
  h         # remove last character
            # (so hs effectively divides by 10)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-x`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

The straightforward solution of adding 8 and floor dividing by 10 would be a byte shorter: `+8 zA`. But where's the fun in that?!

```
õ_ìÌ¶2
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=9V/szLYy&input=MTAw)

```
õ_ìÌ¶2     :Implicit input of integer U
õ          :Range [1,U]
 _         :Map
  ì        :  To digit array
   Ì       :  Last element
    ¶2     :  Is equal to 2?
           :Implicit output of sum of resulting array
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> 7 bytes

```
ṾṪ=”2)S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzn0Pd66yfdQw10gz@P///8YGAA)

But there's already 2 shorter answers I hear you say... Well, this doesn't use mathematics but rather uses strings

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 11 bytes

```scala
n=>(n+8)/10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnkFpRkpqXUqzgWFBQzVWWmKOQZqXgmVeiYGsHof7n2dpp5GlbaOobGvw31CvJ1zA0MNDUS8svSk1MztDIBCksKMrMK8nJA3K0FZRAAkpARppGpqamJlftfwA)

Comment: [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnkFpRkpqXUqzgWFBQzVWWmKOQZqXgmVeiYGsHof7H62lrWGjqGxr8N9QrydcwNDDQ1EvLL0pNTM7QyAQpKyjKzCvJyQNytBWUQAJKQEaaRqampiZX7X8A): `_.+(8)/10`

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 17 bytes

```c
f(n){n=(n+8)/10;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchBCoAgEADAu69YAmEXlYwIAquXdAnF2ENbRDfp7dYcJ7o9xlozChWZUcxIbefDW4@NBamofN7I8gDPPvDUD8EYJgVw3f9mbHQCt4BOqzSWLWRkoqDe@gE)

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>18</del> 17 bytes

```php
<?=$argn/10+.8|0;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt5WJbEoPU/f0EBbz6LGwPr/f0OTf/kFJZn5ecX/dd0A)

-1 bytes thanks to @oxgeba

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 17 bytes

```c
f(n){n+=8;n/=10;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zOk/b1sI6T9/W0MC69n9mXolCbmJmnkZZfmaKJlc1lwIQFBQBhdM0lFRTYvKUdBTSNAw1Na2xyxjhlDHFKWNogFsKt3lGuHUZ45YyNcEpZWmOx4VgE2v/AwA)

Alternative 17-byter:

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 17 bytes

```c
f(n){n=n/10.+.8;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zOs82T9/QQE9bz8K69n9mXolCbmJmnkZZfmaKJlc1lwIQFBQBhdM0lFRTYvKUdBTSNAw1Na2xyxjhlDHFKWNogFsKt3lGuHUZ45YyNcEpZWmOx4VgE2v/AwA)

Alternative 17-byter

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 17 bytes

```c
f(n){n=(n+8)/10;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zOs9WI0/bQlPf0MC69n9mXolCbmJmnkZZfmaKJlc1lwIQFBQBhdM0lFRTYvKUdBTSNAw1Na2xyxjhlDHFKWNogFsKt3lGuHUZ45YyNcEpZWmOx4VgE2v/AwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 28 bytes

```clj
(defn e[n](int(/(+ n 8)10)))
```

Ungolfed:

```clj
(defn ends-in-two [n]
  (int (/ (+ n 8) 10)))
```

Test harness:

```clj
(println (e 1))
(println (e 2))
(println (e 5))
(println (e 10))
(println (e 12))
(println (e 20))
(println (e 30))
(println (e 54))
(println (e 97))
(println (e 100))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv3/XyMlNS1PITU6L1YjM69EQ19DWyFPwULT0EBTU5OLy1ohJLW4RCEjsSgvtbjYikujoAioKidPQSNVwRCoAJlvhMY3ReODjEQVQNdhhK7CGF3A1ARNwNIcwxagnv//AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>18</s> 15 bytes

Thanks @Giuseppe! Guess I didn't really know what the %/% operator did.

```r
(scan()+8)%/%10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/X6M4OTFPQ1PbQlNVX9XQ4L8hlxGXKZehAZehEZeRAZexAZepCZelOVDE4D8A)

Comment: [15 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/X6M4OTFPQ1PbQlNVX9XQ4L8hlxGXKZehAZehEZeRAZexAZepCZelOVDE4D8A)?

Comment: `%/%` is integer division -- see [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Arithmetic.html) for details, under "Value" :-)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>22</s> 18 bytes

```python
lambda n:(n+8)//10
```

Thanks to @JoKing for suggesting to use integer division.

Comment: This approach can be generalized for any digits 0..9. To note 8 = 10-2 then we can rewrite the function in this way `lambda n,d: (n+10-d)//10`.

Comment: Where  `d` is the digit to find in sequence.

Answer (score 2):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 6 bytes

GolfScript has no decimal support, that's why the `/` works.

```
~8+10/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v85C29BA//9/SwMA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

```
/+8QT
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X1/bIjDk/39DIwA)

#### Explanation

```
/+8QT
   Q   : Variable containing evaluated input
 +8    : Add 8 to it
/   T  : Divide result of add by 10
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Javascript (node)](https://nodejs.org/en/) - 25 Bytes

```
f=n=>n?(n%10==2)+f(n-1):0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc7LCoMwEIXhvU@RjZAgyky8FIVpn0WsKYpMpIqvH8FAFzVZf3DOP/dHvw3fad1ztu/ROUNMT35JThGItMqM5BxVB26wvNllLBb7kcJIVIJIgFDJH@gL8A51DBCi4sd04AViUnopAwHVJc1d2ocvgFAc/Myd)

Comment: -1 byte: `f=n=>n&&(n%10==2)+f(n-1)`

Comment: [13 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1k4jT9tCU9/QoMbgf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66hkKahqGmgq2tgoGCJheahBFYwhBTwhSXhKEBThmIYUZYbDHAJWMMkTHG4gATsIwZpoylOcQFBtgcZwCX@w8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 15 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>(n+8)/10|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctLCsMgEADQq8xS6SQdbUIswex6itKFFc2HoEGDq97dttsHbzPFZJvW42yKqsUkCO@UQcNToMQeBaGQKAlvhH2H9@En9Bqr10FPLFwUvwr6UP2v1sf0MHZhDvQENoYcd9fucWaeOc75WL8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 bytes

```
8+A/
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=8%2BA%2F&i=22)

Just a standard add 8, integer divide by 10

Answer (score 2):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 7 bytes

```
8|+10|/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/Z@TV/3fokbb0KBG/39tbG6p339DLiMuUy5DAy5DIy4jAy5jAy5TEy5Lc6CIAQA)

Using [RGS's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200364/91386)

```
8|+  # Add 8 (Parse string implcit)
10|/ # Divide by 10
```

## Burlesque, 10 bytes

```
riq[~GO2CN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/Z@TV/2/KLMwus7d38jZ739tbG6p339DLiMuUy5DAy5DIy4jAy5jAy5TEy5Lc6CIAQA)

```
ri   # Read int
q[~  # Boxed tail (last digit)
GO   # Generate from 1, N
2CN  # Count number of 2's
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Rail](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Rail), 87 bytes

```
$'main'
 -0(!a!)-/-(a)ia(!a!)\
#od[01]a*8(a)-\ /e-----@
@-(!a!)/      >-
  \m(a)[01]--/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0rMzPn/X0U9NzEzT51LQddAQzFRUVNXX1cjUTMzEcyJ4VLOT4k2MIxN1LIAiurGKOin6oKAA5eDLliFvgIY2OlyKSjE5ALVgFTr6ur//29oZGwIAA)

#### Explanations:

```
0(!a!)         Put 0 into variable "a"
(a)ia(!a!)     Add "a" with input (one number at a time), put into variable "a"
e              check if it's EOF, then go left or right at the next junction

               if false:
[10](a)m(!a!)  multiply "a" by 10, put into variable "a"

               if true:
(a)8a[10]do#   add a with 8, then divide by 10, print the output. Fin.

The rest of symbols are tracks
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 18 bytes

```erlang
f(N)->(N+8)div 10.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy3KScxL100tTi7KLCj5z/U/TcNPU9dOw0/bQjMls0zB0EDvf25iZp5GdCxQmEtBITPfqrwosyRVIxrIUVBI0zDU1FFQVdC1UzCAChjBBAyhAqboAoYGmjqoAkZQASOYGQZoAsYwAWOYoSZQATOogKU5zFADuDUGmgiRWE29/wA)

## Explanation

```erlang
f(N)->  % Function taking N as input
(N+8)   % Add input by 8
div 10. % Floor division by 10
```

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 43 bytes

```
=SUM(1*(RIGHT(ROW(OFFSET(A1,0,0,A1)))="2"))
```

`OFFSET(A1,0,0,A1)` generates a range starting at `A1` that is `A1's value` rows tall.
`ROW(OFFSET(~))` returns an array of row numbers for that range (\$[1,N]\$).
`RIGHT(ROW(~))` returns an array of the right-most character of those row numbers as a string.
`RIGHT(~)="2"` returns an array of TRUE or FALSE.
`1*(~)` transforms TRUE to 1 and FALSE to 0.
`SUM(~)` sums.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
8+ĳ∖
```

the easy solution.

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `Ms`, 6 bytes

```
ƛSt\2=
```

-2 bytes from Lyxal.

### Explanation

```
ƛSt\2=
ƛ      map range 1..n to the following:
 S     convert to string
  t    get last character 
   \2= is it equal to '2'?
       sum the results(s flag)
```

Comment: `ƛSt\2=`with `s` flag as well. i.e. Vyxal, `Ms`, 6 bytes

Comment: [Vyxal, `8+Τ⳹`](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?s=?flags=&code=8%2B%CE%A4%E2%B3%B9&inputs=97&header=&footer=)

Comment: [Vyxal, `ƛSt\2=`](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?s=?flags=Ms&code=%C6%9BSt%5C2=&inputs=97&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 3 bytes

```
+₈k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3wX/tRU0f2///RhjpGOqY6hgY6hkY6RgY6xgY6piY6luZAEYNYAA)

Since Brachylog likes to treat integers as lists of decimal digits when appropriate, the "remove last element" builtin `k` can be used to floor-divide by 10.

Answer (score 2):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 24 bytes

```
method(i,((i-1)/10)ceil)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxNDoIwEIWv8tLVTDJCixKjCTdxY7ANk1RqoPcvg4vv/S2elpbwnPBq31iX8iEVIr0E7oPnOWrmlnWvFASDYBQEb1gczK/GeBM87ufuGals8T0vdgJyiRy6DnqKY0z410TKjN@ma80rtwM)

1 byte saved, thanks to xigoi

Comment: -1 byte by using `((i-1)/10)ceil` instead of `((i+8)/10)floor`

Answer (score 2):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), <strike>29</strike> 28 bytes

```
func f[I](n:I):I=(n+8)div 10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYhBCoAgFAX3neLRSukv1IpK6ACeIVpZkot@ENT17bcYZhjOZynp4Yi0hFWxD9qHWXEz6i2/sKak6wYjMxZLcISe5AqSTtwKfUeYhv@b1VfAHo8LTKg9akJSrMsH)

Comment: Oh, I heard about Nim ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 13 bytes

```
[ 8 + 10 /i ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoVBQlFpSUllQlJlXolCcWliampecWqxgzVWtYKhgpGCqYGigYGikYGSgYGygYGqiYGkOFDFQqP0frWChoA2S1c9UiP2fm1igoPcfAA)

It's a quotation (anonymous function) that adds 8 to its input and then (integer) divides it by 10.

Answer (score 2):

## [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), 14 bytes

```
⌊.1*#+.8⌋&
```

RGS did most of the work by coming up with the clever function to determine the answer.  Putting it into Wolfram Langage was then trivial.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6ZgqxDz/1FPl56hlrK2nsWjnm61/wFFmXkl0WnRhgYGsbH/AQ)

NB:

⌊ = \[LeftFloor] = U+230A (3 bytes)

⌋ = \[RightFloor] = U+230B (3 bytes)

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 9 bytes

Prompts for integer n:

+/2=10|⍳⎕

[Try it online! Courtesy of Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/5r6xvZGhrUPOrdDJT4DxT6n8ZlZAgA)

Comment: This only works if ⎕IO is 1. Does that need to be a part of the program?

Comment: @mappo The default ⎕IO setting of my APL+WIN is 1. Similarly it seems that Dyalog Classic in TIO  defaults to ⎕IO = 1. Generally ⎕IO is a session setting and not part of any function. It can be localised within a function if desired to over-ride the session setting.

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
8+I/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@b2j030LbU/9/wX8A)

This is a dc "function": it pops the input from the stack, and then pushes the output onto the stack.  (dc is a stack-based language.)

To call it, enter the desired input first (to push it on the stack), follow with the code above, and then enter `p` to print the output.

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Unix utilities, 13 bytes

```bash
dc<<<$1d8+I/p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PyXZxsZGxTDFQttTv@D///@GRgA)

The input is passed as an argument, and the output is printed.

(This just uses my dc answer internally.)

Answer (score 1):

## AWK, 17 bytes

```
$1=int($1/10+.8)e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fxdA2M69EQ8VQ39BAW89CM/X/f0MuIy5TLkMDLkMjLiMDLmMDLlMTLktzoIgBAA)

This substitutes the input `$1` for the formula `int($1/10+.8)`, and also appends the `e` variable, which is null (not defined variables return null). This causes `$1` to become a string, preventing the expression from evaluating `0` when input is `0` or `1`. A false pattern wouldn't allow the line to be printed (`0` is false).

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 11 bytes

```java
n->(n+8)/10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7NasMwEITvfoohYJCpotppQ3/S5FjooaccQw6qbZl1bdlI65QQ/OyunLbQwzDfLsPO1vqkl3XxOVHbd45Rh1kNTI0yg82ZOqveLL/@8ibKG@093nGJgH74aCiHZ83BTh0VaDVZsWdHtjocoV3lk2sU@HflJXBZlW4Hg@1klzthbx6T2yyd5uDmGjedgyDLIDzDll8IfDheMomVxFoiS4MCroLfBa3vJZ4e5n064q8T2J89l63qBlZ9eIqNWBgRFwm2iIvYLiRIwijd981ZUJL8lI/RrHH6Bg)

Answer (score 1):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), 18 bytes

```
{(it+8).intdiv 10}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYvNCoMwEITvPsWQ0y4G8RfrwScpvdktC5JIkICUPnu6Hj5m5oP5pBjzVba3QNbyJT3rBzcazk0zuvZXJCZSaMCz8@g9Jm/asNpbDsY0eizz7dsXV8CR7L8HckIONdRwjBX3EFLm8gc)

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 13 bytes

```
{a->(a+8)/10}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY2xCsIwFEV3v@LSKSGvmFSLWmzB0cnBL8iS8jCmkkZBSr89BlzucA6c@5iS55DdO@BpOQgbx7nDJUb7Pd9T5DAOEssG@FgP14lrSLIeyqLPi60HYdVRbo1eM@CmCMHgAM9zujlhqKGWjCbTUKNpp6nd0@lQiJb/KvAqH8kHUTlRKVaVRI9KOcFSFr9u1vwD)

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>29</s> <s>21</s> <s>20</s> 17 bytes

```
f(n){n=(n+8)/10;}
```

#### [Try It Online](https://tio.run/##HY7BCsIwEETv/YpBKSQ01aRaVNL2R7QHSawGdCu1nkq/PW5dGN4yw7Dr8rtzcR3IPb/@huoz@tBvHk3sBMmJakHZUW6NtnMMNOJ1DSQkpgQ8i0Fno1vUmIxCoVAqGM3itWDuWOVe4XRYfD3b5F/s@kEs5cBFbRkVp8wsk3gPnHRilXrkeYPUX2il@ExoFfgnppQWyRx/)

Which works only if optimizations are turned off ([more info](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106067/100356)).
If you love optimizations, then I got this **18 bytes** solution for you:

```
#define N (n+8)/10
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##PU3bCoJAFHz3KwZFUFxrraTCyyf4A@VDuFoLeQzTJ/Hb7WxSA8Mchpk5VXivqsXRVD1HVSN9D0p3m0e@OKpuNNUo4FFw8reRXDQNaG@aPB@TBYYxaGwvkSyRYYoEdgKxQCSZfO5Y98z4IHA@Gl/OApRY33bT9Z5Z0NyVCUvKAdYg@O0bUGY@6DL5O6@eW41nuwphmMNVV7IF1pRA4a/J2ZqXDw)

Comment: It's not golfed ;)

Comment: You mean that `(n+8)/10;` is not a valid answer? The answer should read the input and print the output?

Comment: In code-golf you should implement either a function or a program. In this case program would take n as input and print the result to output and function would take n as argument and return the result.

Comment: All right thank you very much for the explanation! If I choose a function, do I need to count even the declaration `int countTwos( int n ) {` or can I limit the count to the body of the function?

Comment: You need to write a full function or a full program in a minimal amout of bytes/characters. So I'd use `int f(int n){`. ;)

Comment: all right thank you! :)

Comment: YW ;) can you please edit your answer? ;)

Comment: Sure, I am working on it. I need to include in the count even white spaces, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, white spaces count too.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did it!

Comment: Yea, that's a well-golfed answer. Thank you ;)

Comment: Thank You! It's nice to golf :)

Comment: -1 byte: `int f(int n){return(n+8)/10;}`

Comment: Oh thank you so much! I didn't know I could do it

Answer (score 1):

## [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/), 12 bytes

```
n->(n+8)//10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85Pzs8rLfmfpmCrEPM/T9dOI0/bQlNf39Dgf7ShjoKRjoKpjoKhARADmUZA2hiITU10FCzNQeIGsQoxXDV2CrmJBSoaeQq6dgoFRZl5JRp5OgppGnmampoKQEmgDcWluan/AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, 8 bytes

```
int(.1(N+8
```

There are a handful of equivalent solutions here because of the number of ways you can do implicit multiplication by .1 - there's also a solution available using the default value of Xmax from the graphscreen variables.

```
int(.1N+.8

int(N/Xmax+.8
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 44 bytes

```
->x{(1..x).to_a.map{|e|(e%10)==2?1:0}.sum}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcxBCoAgEIXh/ZzCTaCLBrUiCqyjxBTujKISiurstp6WH@/nbXG8UiLhhATIu/OWBvFUeCwD4Uzr/fhH@sxo5ZztTatf3OP8AiiANR67IJwoBGGYLFPFS83JW8vXgrMqGZv696whpQ8)

I don't use Ruby very often, I'm sure it can be golfed further.

Answer (score 1):

## [Risky](https://github.com/Radvylf/risky), 3.5 bytes

```
?++//+/
```

[Try it online!](https://radvylf.github.io/risky?p=WyI_KysvLysvIiwiWzk3XSIsMF0)

Answer (score 1):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 35 bytes

```
(load library
(d y(q((n)(/(+ 8 n)10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8nMq8zJLC74/18jJz8xRSEnM6kosaiSSyNFoVKjUEMjT1NDX0NbwUIhT9PQ4L9GpYKhgYHmfwA)

Luckily, `library` had a builtin for division.

Answer (score 0):

## [Knight](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 17 bytes

```c
OUTPUT/+8PROMPT10
```

My first submission for the language of the month; Knight, which I just found out was a thing. Implements the same function as my previous Haskell (and basically everyone else's) answer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltU9tIEv5s/4rBKSyNLQdJcFUpG5kiWUhRR4Dl5fYD@IKQZVCtLPskGZYj3F/Pdfe8aGSb3OVu@WBZM0/3dD/T091jot59FH1/l2RRuhjHu0U5TmbvH4ZNcyRN7mpDUfk8j5dAeZLd14bKZCow43iSZDFLU5bOsnv6aOrRy5OrL8yrXi8uz5lfvf5t/5ztVK@HJ5/Yh@r1/Ip5Ffjw@MLAnlwdG9Crky/7F3@1C85s/Gizf3l/4Xp2/wKWFZPRQ5izDq8ETBTYqlUMh2ynmjs5@A0nM5gkj74x/L67u4TBZQiDbgImTTkCa5iPp6fHBMKPPXKyj74Zhpx/FgCQN2x9DNNFzPl1NuLNJvkBu3I9Cs5bB6eH9vfTq8uzq8ut7oez89MvZ5ee@53DeGsgoB3AxuGUBSg0aDZB8zzMi9jm7KXZSLKSJYNmA0ZpFYd1JossghESjuC9nM6dYp5d@6PgxXXcV9DRSEAd4eHp4sDWFqpP5uzpISnjYh5GcbMB39PYhnEQt4UZDmvdlDfZzeQmZy@v1yOb99@1OJnSSCbM1tYGzHpncSZUqNENGL3JYLjbFSNgZyNOi9gceBXmRA9x9DubzHKWLaZ3cV5Ie5idFOPkPimVVlgd3fEc7ZF4dpjnsi7rSMu7Xc56zHItWAItTTjL43KRZ0zFhRCj0Bgs2/AY5kl4l8bKCjAinT3FuR3BesoQ9u0bU8ZF9BYREV8tLulJ1rieBJ4DexTo4SXr8KTJiARINl7MbdxSJjntMXhbNVic@0JoE2bcWFZlU8sSmwbC4IE2ioESyBPwHSybh0XJyocYlIV5CWC5AR3FKG5oxNETZaxxfN40Fj49ThvdqMgg8zF0y2SWgdkYse4ITIsUI8ViPkfCuYoqNWLSb8Yf0G6QjTpUKM8ziGPIWRi50nLByqWlD7YYOMQBzF99zFtopgoySnnCVRvtRlPDNJ1F9o7reBwdxGHtBDmYLdI0zJ9NR6v9OTe258zSltGCUn6RLUnTEh4uIZPCOk/3Dz5@uv114/iXU8NhU@1dslavv6p3o6b489HFGxrLOCeVYTZm/1iE6hXVPppLbK8uIQj4bGkujtZwQcI7deE65pVSZb7IcIcGMu92yllhq1xJBwBCu0wiRrN3i8m1vzOSdoiNblN60AYUczhW5cQGKPi/mabjlso7VHccVLKsAA6FViAqmli/httl3nbdT3QeY3GPtcp8EbcgBvU4hiSMT0LIIDjRwshqVSSgn@i7LD1Ex9ePs1kKM3d1Bt70tXLrRw51ft4j08y7FTNTtDH7U22EoC1naWqbpjrMdaBC/A8mZysmYxX@sn924mAtFoEGr0fXnuu6EE7gCryqtyL5Z/y1ZPgYGDFqeIsMwJuDHz59bgeeKumY4bCq44M@ffHYBsDh0fFBh00gOQ4aOrTlepiGo3DupHFGHYDBleqMBGdw7t4iY1kQaxOWNiw4dkK9BNTiXeJiAEUlwUmdN6LpfGkHiKRkVKUQpCkZ4TLFU1JGD3YHmFlppIAjJv8irFPWvtVnuIoABEgotmKQhXmbnJLqZTNYC1k@oCpcIajjLHMsXdR0Xo/4SxVm0EBRbhcLn8PCdd05ZDybt90/JvhXIc8ACVoFR/dxmUK/aLdpL9u4Q1gix0nGB8nEtmk/sSGIHnK0xYE45Vxsc@AO1toKD05tgFjvQKwnOkfMBpKQgbIXSZK5s7LyY@WPwOuZT9UMSpoUa8wtYDAaIP6C@WweZ7axsNPKW9QqgFXBVFRKiMfAd3c@0LhsLmzRkUzA9DE6BS0chKyD/R3AoXegN1wDllbhZcMg6wbUCuGJBSSXdIMeWouoRg2dgPlmz1LRWHnyK3gS/wFtHJ72FT83artO14INzGQrwOOV8IBV0jovBvwXqy/7xDWBrDOfrECtE2qLbaxBXBWh4XCHV43lSjpUohfUHNqbBQrWD8OqMNAJrY@5LmRS3qqgagLLSxxmUu1bJUzWLHMHZG6RLJxWLODBEBcfJE3sZ4061m7TXarXQ@hItLk31G43lFmb7zsF2GPDG2fqqOWG@YuyULuvY0L0esKgrjaI8iTkS0zJGFrG9ohuulHfbXExRTT0/UzFki/2HPtfOgxiAwiFw3jKA@Wlz9eHahSW6iG7Tq9b0cTVd9TFoRt16FnKHCH96q1EpxHt2KrX7RVCnWp31rCwXJ7X8NBZ4UHs6zoWpmtc6xAmMJWQANQgmzJkYN3AJQ9Bg16P9EmiqGQub7RgtKyd/q0fErO1npjNHwptrhf6O7FZc0hcHWjMN70cSNoF6wHreZplwgL1HpyzngdnzDPB/k@idyE91rBBgFBat69GXEU5Ee0PXcm1z6ld6QTEf3P5QNAkuQJ3BEqwWGLgO14ZHuI8tgqWzaCHTtIyydhT@Ay8sfEM7qRlfB/nIDOfZXFWJiHeIuAkz9hTzB7CxxiAUhHCSzYNswWEz/N7HEXv7pBxoIKYKBZpiT8a0OI64SlIz8SoJZcoM@U0ZEk96nsb6b5tiIbt1lAu3c/DFGvjM3idjdN4zG4rs2@1lhf8JhozY5HKmSEq6/XUOyd4Q0I7humvOg/uUrAuFT5MerW8GNSz4h4zD/@ueQxQtC9/cmszAdhjtUaRBh1mZEPU4QpJVXJ9UQcQuxFAtTG6oCEcSgyt2XjWZ9N4Gs0xzDI2vN37f10Z/gmuDJUrG2t8CaQv0pW9t9kXq64xGaf3WA3ga4SvCujGOjurF@2eyjymAm1eu0p/6Mu62rBnSspUouW//TfyMgcZarT8wOqb6Fqbu4wNqqxbn/7pi4zqbaubDOIatduMToWEQY2joCZtpEmUQES3q8WEyb@Be@JXL7PRrHnHzN5Fih3Vu3aEGvJ7fn/boOWzuDIERofVNQvQ6h0pkxcPR5@F7VpDeyGIXlI6WC55/rqSt811H@Br6R0a/A8NERqGT9yKSDf/uh0yeyMfPMRVux42SdQgiPgXk/QgRFeeBFh9HE9CSJLgmeowkwwmkzH9iBRGJZQpazOysOfEEc7euMWiMl0DoRuUPyRMwyTDZpWF@X3kkNJOB74/cvy5iu6X@B8c2yVr6te41@87/wY) (online interpreter implemented in TIO in C)

Comment: You can just do `O/+8P10`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
8+T÷
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWSy20Qw5vX1KclFwMFVmw2NDAAMIEAA) Port of RGS's Python answer.

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `L`, 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
æ2ø>
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0ko9S7IKlpSVpuhbLDi8zOrzDbklxUnIxVGjBYkMDAwgTAA) Literal solution.

##### Explanation

```python
8+T÷  # Implicit input
8+    # Add 8 to the input
  T÷  # Floor divide by 10
      # Implicit output
```

```python
æ2ø>  # Implicit input
æ     # Filter [1..input] by:
 2ø>  #  Ends with 2
      # Push the length
      # Implicit output
```