# Help, I've mixed my week up!

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity, date, sorting

My dog ate my calendar, and now my days are all mixed up. I tried putting it back together, but I keep mixing up the days of the week! I need some help putting my calendar back together, with the days in the correct order.

And since I need my calendar put together as fast as possible, don't waste my time by sending me superfluous bytes. The fewer bytes I have to read, the better!

### Input

The days of the week, in any order. Input can be taken as a list of strings, or a space separated string, or any reasonable way of representing 7 strings (one for each day of the week).

The strings themselves are all capitalized, as weekdays should be, so the exact strings are:

```
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday
```

### Output

The days of the week, in sorted order (Monday - Sunday, because of course we adhere to ISO 8601). Output can be as a list of strings, or printed with some delimiter.

### Disclaimer

Note that this is a [kolmogorov-complexity](/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) challenge, with the added benefit of being able to use the input to shorten your code. You are not required to use the input if you don't want to. You are also free to use any approach, from a builtin datetime library to hard-coding the output.

### Examples

To see example input and output, you can consult [this python script](https://tio.run/##dYxLCsMgFEXnrkIyUgiZdCZkAR11CeG1T4lUn@IHdPVpoMmgpZ3ec86NvayBLttmfQyp8Ac4TQiJmdmBvyPwpvIONIo2PnU/V1TO5iJOfULoC4HXcrKEugmU8rxMQBg8y2s1xmlcdjXzmf/p2VufDl18ZJLFZKmI4UqxFjWM/De@1XJw83Ugtxc).

Comment: I hope you've learnt your lesson from this: never leave dogs with calendars.

Comment: any delimiter allowed?

Comment: @Helena I'd say any delimiter within reason. I'd prefer space, comma, or newline, but if the language you're using has another default separator, or you'll be able to knock off a few bytes, go for it. Though I will specify that it has to be the *same* separator between all output words.

Comment: I hope you have learnt your lesson from this: it is a dog-eat-calendar world.

Comment: in any order = in random order? because thats what many of the answers seem to be assuming

Comment: @ASCII-only The program should work for any of the \$7!\$ different ways to order the days of the week. I used a random shuffle in my example code just to show that the output order is independent of the input order.

Answer (score 20):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 7 bytes

```
o%CN258
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P1/V2c/I1OL//2il4NK8lMRKJR2lkNLUYggrOLGktAgqmFFaBBV1K8qEMMJTU/JgSn3zwbpjAQ)

Convert each string to a number via treating its ASCII codes as a base 256 number, then take that mod 258, and sort. This gives the mapping

```
['Monday', 49]
['Tuesday', 75]
['Wednesday', 89]
['Thursday', 99]
['Friday', 103]
['Saturday', 125]
['Sunday', 211]
```

Same length but less fun is

```
.P1314S
```

The 1314th permutation of the sorted input in lexicographic order.

Comment: How did you find that?

Comment: @Adam I just searched the first 1000 moduluses and got very lucky. On average, it should take over 5040 (7!) moduluses to find one that gives a specific ordering, but this one appears quite early.

Comment: If you ask people "how did you find that", they probably just brute-forced.

Comment: I wanted to wait a bit before posting my own solution, but you had the exact same idea that I had (and you did it with 7 bytes instead of 8). Good solution!

Answer (score 10):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org),  <s>37 36</s>  35 bytes

<sup>*This should also work in Chrome and Edge (Chromium)*</sup>

Returns a list of strings.

```javascript
a=>a.sort().sort(_=>-(a=a*595|5)%7)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3NCoJAGEX3PsW3iZmpHNpIlIzgJmghLRJaRMSHP6nYjIwzQdC7248a1OqeC4d7K7xhm@iyMa5UadblokMRIG@VNpT1cRaBS1Hg1Ft5D49NlqwLQcARSKRkincyBxLbrB3wkKXyW@LC6pE3uhxoj8bqke1nA06@Ew5/IAKI0BRco0zVlTJwYcE95juJkq2qM16rCyVb2VgDayAwg5BXqpT0Pcj@vZ01L7H3chqyH7V7Ag)

#### How?

We first sort the input array in lexicographical order. Whatever the input is, we get:

```
Friday, Monday, Saturday, Sunday, Thursday, Tuesday, Wednesday
```

We then invoke `sort()` a second time with a callback function that, while ignoring its input, generates a sequence of positive and negative values in such a way that the underlying sorting algorithm (insertion sort) is tricked into putting the array in the desired order.

Below is a summary of all steps. Note that because of the bitwise OR, the value stored in \$a\$ is always coerced to a signed 32-bit integer (and so are the 3rd and 4th columns in this table).

```
  A  |  B  | previous a  | -(a*595|5)  | mod 7 | new order
-----+-----+-------------+-------------+-------+-----------------------------------
 Fri | Mon |  NaN        | -5          |  -5   | Mon Fri Sat Sun Thu Tue Wed
 Mon | Sat |  5          | -2975       |   0   | unchanged
 Fri | Sat |  2975       | -1770125    |   0   | unchanged
 Fri | Sun |  1770125    | -1053224375 |   0   | unchanged
 Sat | Sun |  1053224375 |  396722091  |   3   | unchanged
 Sat | Thu | -396722091  | -173557135  |  -3   | Mon Fri Thu Sat Sun Tue Wed
 Fri | Thu |  173557135  | -187280221  |  -2   | Mon Thu Fri Sat Sun Tue Wed
 Mon | Thu |  187280221  |  237418201  |   6   | unchanged
 Fri | Tue | -237418201  | -470091173  |  -6   | Mon Thu Tue Fri Sat Sun Wed
 Thu | Tue |  470091173  | -531373695  |  -6   | Mon Tue Thu Fri Sat Sun Wed
 Mon | Tue |  531373695  |  1660231379 |   2   | unchanged
 Fri | Wed | -1660231379 | -4807575    |  -3   | Mon Tue Thu Wed Fri Sat Sun
 Tue | Wed |  4807575    |  1434460171 |   4   | unchanged
 Thu | Wed | -1434460171 | -1194690159 |  -5   | Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
```

Comment: This relies on Node's specific sorting algorithm, so it's not generic ES6.

Comment: Woot. I think that means I'm winning the generic JavaScript category (39 characters). That never happens. :) Still, never thought of using only one argument in the `sort` callback, that's...nuts.

Comment: Wait, you're not using *either* argument. So whacky.

Comment: FWIW, in FireFox for me it gives the wrong answer: [ "Saturday", "Sunday", "Friday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Thursday", "Wednesday" ]

Comment: @SteveBennett Ah, you're right. I've added a note to clarify.

Comment: @Arnauld Not sure what you mean by all major JS engines, as I get Wednesday, Monday, Thursday, Tuesday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday in Safari.

Comment: @Neil Hopefully I got it right, this time. :p

Comment: Yeah, that's much better, thanks.

Comment: Ooh, I have equalled 37 characters with a much more straightforward and also cross-platform solution. :)

Comment: Two more characters, nice one!

Comment: @SteveBennett I got a bit lucky with this last pattern, as `-(a=a*595|5)%7` is the _only_ expression of this form that produces the correct sequence.

Answer (score 9):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 2 bytes

Pyke has some weird constant built-ins (a link to the Stack Exchange API, the lengths of months as numbers, the names of the days of the week and so on).

```
~C
```

Doesn't take input.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6jMTv3/v875/38A)

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to beat this

Comment: I won't be surprised if there is some language I forgot about with a 1-byter for this.

Answer (score 7):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/) 18.0 beta, 19 bytes

Full program, taking no input.

```apl
'Dddd'(1200⌶)⍳7
```

Returns a list of strings:

```apl
┌──────┬───────┬─────────┬────────┬──────┬────────┬──────┐
│Monday│Tuesday│Wednesday│Thursday│Friday│Saturday│Sunday│
└──────┴───────┴─────────┴────────┴──────┴────────┴──────┘
```

`⍳7` Integers 1…7, representing the dates Jan 1–7, 1900

`(1200⌶)` [Format Date-time](https://help.dyalog.com/18.0/#Language/Primitive%20Operators/Format%20Datetime.htm) ("12:00") as follows:

`'Dddd'` long **D**ay name

Comment: I get a domain error when trying the code online: `line(1,0) : error AC0008: error (DOMAIN ERROR) executing line "'Dddd'(1200⌶)⍳7" `

Comment: @maxb I forgot to remove the TIO link as TIO is on 17.1. Works locally by me. I'll add a link to the docs instead.

Comment: "The Nineteenth Byte"

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript, 37 characters

```js
e=>[...'1564023'].map(a=>e.sort()[a])
```

### JavaScript, 38 characters

```js
e=>[1,5,6,4,0,2,3].map(a=>e.sort()[a])
```

### Javascript, 39 characters

```js
e=>e.map((a,i)=>e.sort()['1564023'[i]])
```

### Javascript, 45 characters

```js
e=>e.map((a,i)=>e.sort()[[1,5,6,4,0,2,3][i]])
```

### Javascript, 51 characters

```js
e=>(v=e.sort(),v.map((a,i)=>v[[1,5,6,4,0,2,3][i]]))
```

### Javascript, 52 characters

```js
e=>(v=e.sort(),[v[1],v[5],v[6],v[4],v[0],v[2],v[3]])
```

### Javascript, 61 characters

I tried a couple of things, but they were fractionally longer than:

```js
z=>'Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday'
```

Comment: The 54 is 52 because the `z=` shouldn't have been included in the count.

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible to do `e=>e.map((_,n)=>e.sort()[some_magic_with(n)])` instead, but that seems unlikely. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Yeah, I pondered something along those lines. There's about 8 characters to play with (assuming the magic is going to contain `n` and we want 36 characters or fewer total).

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>40</s> 38 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to xnor*

```python
from calendar import*;print(*day_name)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1chOTEnNS8lsUghM7cgv6hEy7qgKDOvREMrJbEyPi8xN1Xz/38A)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>44</s> 43 bytes

```python
lambda d:sorted(d,key=lambda x:~hash(x)%72)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYqxCsIwFEX3fsVbhAScuhQKXd2cKjioyJMkJqgv4SXBdvHXYxudzuGeG@ZkPbXFDOfyxNdNIag@ek5aCbV96Hn4r1P/sRitmOSma2VROEcY4MT4vjoKOQkJxjM4cASMdNeik5cmsKMERqx3WcZMizR7X3HIOlbazFV27FYctaJfGTFlXuQL)

Comment: The perfect built-in! I think `from calendar import*;print(*day_name)` would be allowed.

Comment: By the way, I've been looking for a solution similar to your sorting one, but with an object method for the key so as to avoid writing a lambda. I had hopes for `"...".strip` or `"...".translate`, but it seems none of those can work. Perhaps you have a better idea with this.

Comment: Thanks for the improvement, I clearly missed that! As for my 2nd answer, I will definitely try to shave off bytes if I can. As you said, the lambda takes up quite a few bytes.

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 21 bytes

Anonymous prefix lambda. Port of [isaacg's Pyth solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204078/43319) — go upvote that!

```apl
{⍵[⍋258|256⊥¨⎕UCS¨⍵]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qW9CjtgmGRhbm/6sf9W6NftTbbWRqUWNkavaoa@mhFUAFoc7BQLp3a2zt/zSg0ke9fY@6mh/1rnnUu@XQeuNHbROBaoKDnIFkiIdn8P80BfXgxJLSopTESnUF9ZCM0qJiCDO4NA8qVpoKFfLNhwqFp6bkwQTdijJBDK40OBOHQoQ5eC0EAA)

`{`…`}` "dfn"; argument is `⍵`:

`⍵[`…`]` reorder the argument into the following order:

`⎕UCS¨⍵` Universal Character Set code points of each string

`256⊥¨` evaluate each in base-256

`258|` the division remainder when divided by 258

`⍋` grade (permutation that would sort it)

Comment: You posted 3 different answers for APL...

Comment: @petStorm Sure, why not? The are completely different in their approaches.

Answer (score 6):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 27 bytes

```java
java.time.DayOfWeek::values
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVHLTsMwELz3K1Y5oISCVa4pBSEQJxCHgjggDkuyKW4dO3jXlSrUby/Og4egEpfMxOPdnR0vcY3Hy3K103XjvMAy/qsg2qjD6ejPWRVsIdrZvSKLJ6xbqTDIDLeoLbyPAJrwYnQBLCgR1k6XUEctnYvXdvH0DOgXnHVXAdbogWNjKq9wwzCDC@8jUcg3miVNbp0tcXN0H4hbfKTS9uz@NfiOXHvdwhwl@I6EtiJR3BgdGxwlWTbtRu3Zax6aeIv8aaeJrklFG3fVI9Hq6fkMqtluj5LnazTR0K7v@@KcIbTAoSiI2x3EB@q1ynlItRXQ8XgyjXAKJ5NJy8bjzwwGa7/HgycORmJhpRYk6bAGfA06mP2IbniPNFM1NkPWeS7uoWnIXyJTpgpnDBWSXvboPCtxXcxZpugtoOH0O6ThIYa2vZe@@d5ILNb/jBj8b7vvfMNCtXJBVBOtirHp51rnkAw0gRySCrVJutrtaLv7AA)

Doing this because the challenge input is very structured, but the output is not structured at all.

## No built-ins, 49 bytes

```java
l->l.sort((a,b)->~a[0]*a[4]%-473-~b[0]*b[4]%-473)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVHLitswFN3nKy6GFmkmFikdKOThUlK66tBFBroIWVzb8kSpLLl6pISS@fWMJNtthwnd6NyHrs49Rwc8Yn6of1xE22nj4BBy5p2Q7GYxeVVrvKqc0Opq0zrDsY2tSqK1cI9Cwe8JQOdLKSqwDl2AoxY1tKFHNs4I9bjdAZpHS9NVgCMasOFhXn/Gk4UVfBXWsUp3p28N@WRMKDK0sUiye61qPE0fPLcRv/Na9dHD3psUfDEiwgadNynwcSJjtpMiPDDNKKWLxHtF5For61tulpFtWe3RbHdFAc3qIvMi6A1bEoLTkubFE25nuxvc3u3e5Hcf3udPZczLMaeXnqTUWnJUYH1VcRvVOeN532u0ASKUAxHKs0WAJbybzWJ0ezu60/sT3QiXFP8FyZG0X0H@2kaHzyCUtdgNRs/nTq@DiDRCg6VS8sqRdY/aWOZ08nW0BGDoBTMss3vfNJKTSP7nQsMwKOncy@oAo8q3q39@lPGfHqVNA9e3DLL@v93Ac07n5mQdb5n2jnVh3klFRt6PkA1hBnPIGhQyS7PnyfnyDA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 27 bytes

```
DayName@{#}&/@198~Range~204
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773yWx0i8xN9WhWrlWTd/B0NKiLigxLz21zsjA5H9AUWZeiYK@Q/r//wA)

Comment: I'm confused. Care to explain?

Comment: @Adám DayName works like this: `DayName[date] `. So I found another way by using integers. Unfortunately the order didn't work for Friday....

Comment: How comes the integers are not representing dates in order?

Comment: I really don't know... range[7] returns `{Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Saturday, Sunday, Monday}`. This is not supposed to work with integers. It's an abuse

Comment: Not really an abuse. The `date` format that `DayName` takes can be `{year,month,day}` (or even have hours/minutes/seconds); or it can be `{year,month}` in which case the day is assumed to be 1 if needed; or it can even be `{year}` in which case the month and day are assumed to be 1 if needed. So this code is calculating the day of the week for 1 January 198, 1 January 199, ... through 1 January 204. I believe it's doing so assuming (wrongly) that our current Gregorian calendar extends back indefinitely. ...

Comment: ... Anyway, it's a convenient coincidence that in non-leap-years, the day of the week of January 1 (or any given date) is one day later then in the previous year. (This is because 365 is 1 more than a multiple of 7.) Unfortunately it's hard to find a stretch of seven consecutive non-leap-years—but it is possible, because 100, 200, 300, 500, 600, 700, 900, ... are not leap years. If we were lucky, we could have saved a byte by finding a range of years around 100 that started with a Monday, but a quick check reveals that the year 96 just gets in the way.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

Port of isaacg's base conversion answer.

```
Σ₁ö29%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3OJHTY2HtxlZqv7/H63kVpSZklippKPkm58HYYSnpuSlFkPYIaUwVnBiSWkRVDCjtAgmWgrWFAsA)

### Explanation

```
Σ      Filter the input by this function:
 ₁ö    Base-convert it from 256
   ₁   Constant 256
    Ì  Add 2 (= 258)
     % Modulo by this number
```

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Expired Data

```
{œŽ5dè
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/@ujko3tNUw6v@F97buvh5V7/o9V98/NSEivVdRTUQ0pTi6HM8NSUPDgnJKO0CMZ2K8qEsoITS0qLYOxSsBmx/wE)

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 21 bytes

```
Σ"TuWeThFrSaSu"2ôåāsÏ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3GKlkNLw1JAMt6LgxOBSJaPDWw4vPdJYfLj///9oJbeizJTESiUdJd/8PAgjPDUlL7UYwg4phbGCE0tKi6CCGaVFMNFSsKbY/wA)

### Explanation

```
Σ                     Sort by the output of this function.
 "TuWeThFrSaSu"2ô     Split every item of that by length of 2.
                 å    Contains?
                  āsÏ Find all truthy indices of that.
```

Comment: [You can get 6 with the other approach too](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/@ujko3tNUw6v@F97buvh5V7/o9V98/NSEivVdRTUQ0pTi6HM8NSUPDgnJKO0CMZ2K8qEsoITS0qLYOxSsBmx/wE "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Comment: `{œŽ5dè` was exactly the same solution I've found o-o

Comment: Using [`ö` instead of `β`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3OJHTY2HtxlZqv7/H63kVpSZklippKPkm58HYYSnpuSlFkPYIaUwVnBiSWkRVDCjtAgmWgrWFAsA) also gives 6 bytes, and doesn't require a footer to pretty-print.

Comment: You can remove the footer in that second approach of _@ExpiredData_ by replacing the `'` in the input-list with `"`: [try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/@ujko3tNUw6v@P8/WsmtKDMlsVJJR8k3Pw/CCE9NyUsthrBDSmGs4MSS0iKoYEZpEUy0FKwpFgA). Also, there is an \$n^{th}\$ permutations builtin `.I`, which is faster than generating all permutations first before indexing: [`{Ž5d.I`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/@uhe0xQ9z///o5XcijJTEiuVdJR88/MgjPDUlLzUYgg7pBTGCk4sKS2CCmaUFsFES8GaYgE) (although it's irrelevant for the byte-count).

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 35 bytes

Anonymous prefix lambda. This one actually sorts its argument and doesn't use any "cheating" built-ins.

```apl
{⍵[⍋((∊∘⎕A⊂⊢)'MoTuWeThFrSa')⍳2↑¨⍵]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pR79boR73dGhqPOroedcx41DfV8VFX06OuRZrqvvkhpeGpIRluRcGJ6pqPejcbPWqbeGgFUEds7f@0R20THvX2PepqftS75lHvlkPrjYGyQO3BQc5AMsTDM/h/moJ6cGJJaVFKYqW6gnpIRmlRMYQZXJoHFStNhQr55kOFwlNT8mCCbkWZIAZXGpyJQyHCHLwWAgA)

`{`…`}` "dfn"; argument is `⍵`:

`⍵[`…`]` reorder the argument into the following order:

`2↑¨` take the first two letters from each input day name

`(`…`)⍳` find the index in the following list (missing items become 1 beyond last index)

`(`…`)'MoTuWeThFrSa'` apply the following tacit function to this string:

`⊢` the argument

`⊂` split on

`∊∘⎕A` membership of the uppercase **A**lphabet

`⍋` grade (permutation that would sort it)

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) `-m32`, 50 bytes

```c
main(i){for(;puts(nl_langinfo(131079+i%7))-i++;);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI1OzOi2/SMO6oLSkWCMvJz4nMS89My8tX8PQ2NDA3FI7U9VcU1M3U1vbWtO69v//f8lpOYnpxf91c42NAA)

### Explanation

Simply put, `nl_langinfo()` is a useful function which returns a particular string given an argument. It just turns out that the argument to pass for obtaining weekday names is `131079 ... 131086`. One other thing is that we must add the flag `-m32`, which is explained nicely in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96555/88546).

Comment: I was really confused by the `-i++` part, does it work because `Sunday` happens to be 6 letters (and the 7th day of the week)? EDIT: In `nl'_langinfo` Sunday is the first day of the week, but your `i%7` seems to handle that.

Comment: The `i` variable starts to 1, and is incremented after every iteration. That means we actually start at `131080` instead of `131079`. This is on purpose, since as you said, `Sunday` is the first day of the week when using `nl_langinfo`. On the last iteration, when `i` equals 7, the number becomes `131079` because of the modulo, printing `Sunday`. The reason it terminates after outputting `Sunday` is because `puts` returns the length of the string (including newline), so `Sunday` returns 7. It also happens that `i` equals 7, so subtracting them exits the loop.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>45</s> 43 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to @xnor!*

```python
lambda l:map(sorted(l).pop,[1,4,4,3,0,0,0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU7LCoMwELznK/ZmhCDa9iR47a2nCj1YDylJasA8WM3Br0@TojKwzCw7s@O3dXL2ElX3jjM3H8Fhbg33dHG4SkHnsvLOs6Fht4QrqzPGMmrj0wEgt8IZwu0CHQzFw1nBt4JB0Qe57PQlhT1FPwU8@B31zp58DXjw8M8YSZo5NWUP7UiIcggatM0/v5I2ddkS2AtUyxSUmiXNnjKvk1GdyqO2qSsD7LoUF38)

Sort by normal string comparison first, then look up the correct permutation.

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 58 bytes

```python
lambda l:sorted(l,key=lambda s:"TuWeThFrSaSu".find(s[:2]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY49C4MwEIb3/IrDxQSk9GMLZO3WSaGDdUhJUkM1kYsZRPztNhbb5Xjuhfe5G6ax9e6yGvFYO9k/lYSOB4@jVrQr3noSexp4VsW7rtorlrKM2cFYp2io@blhbLX9kDqA0infE@kCCKjzm3dKTnkBeRV12PGulfsvVRvxx1e0O5VyjPjj@HU0JM3Nmtw1bwgxHsGCddvNl6anI@ME9gcOoY3GdJpuHbbFqWj@24DWjdRkMy4F1DMKkaRLk7H1Aw)

Use the first 2 letters of each day to look up the order.

Comment: Nice that you skip `Mo`, which results in `-1` for Monday.

Comment: Nice idea with the sorting! Here's [a small byte save](https://tio.run/##PY4/C4MwEMX3fIrbTCCItp0E126dKnSwDilJasD84TSDn94mReXg@L3j3rsL6zJ6d9l0@94mYT9SwNRYEejscVGSTqwMPvC@5rdUV17lGthmbEgLgMJJb4lwM7TQFw/vpFgLDkUX1bzjS0l3im6MePAdzU5PsUQ8OP4zBpJ6Tk3ZfTMQoj2CAePyza@idcUaAvsD5TxGrSdFs4flcTLqUwU0bqHIAds2xbHtBw), though it needs Python 2 since Python 3 produces a map object unless you unpack.

Comment: @xnor Thank you! I was looking at `__getitem__`, but totally forgot about `pop`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 20 bytes

```
day-names 1 rotate .
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcQxCoAwDAXQ3VPkAhZc6wHExUXEObRfELVqEsGevvqGt3CwU8o09kPnKfCOFFlIcT9IAerwmrDSJTDLl6zJqK36wdMMbJGzlr868QGlhuQ0NpAr5QM)

[Factor](https://factorcode.org/) has a built-in sequence for the days of the week, but is starts with Sunday - that's why I need to rotate the items to the right.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 30 bytes

Assuming an English locale

```r
weekdays(as.Date("1/1/1")+0:6)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzw1NTslsbJYI7FYzyWxJFVDyVAfCJU0tQ2szDT//wcA)

January 1st of the year 1 is a Monday (according to R).

Comment: Technically, this only works if your computer is set to a locale such as `en_GB` where the day names are the same as the question's. I think you are allowed to assume any reasonable locale you like for these sorts of challenges so it's not an invalid answer, but you should perhaps say at the top that you are assuming an English locale.

Comment: @JDL Thanks, never thought about that

Answer (score 4):

## T-SQL, 49 bytes

```sql
SELECT DATENAME(w,RANK()OVER(ORDER BY d)-1)FROM t
```

Input is taken as a pre-existing table *t* with varchar column *d*, [per our IO standards](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341).

My code doesn't actually *use* the values in the input table in any way, so the input order doesn't matter (nor do the actual strings, they just have to be distinct). Instead, it uses the fact that it has 7 rows, along with the `RANK()` function, to generate the numbers 1 through 7.

After subtracting 1, these numbers are implicitly cast as dates (0=Mon Jan 1, 0001, 6=Sun Jan 7, 0001), and the `DATENAME` function returns the corresponding day of the week.

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 8 bytes

```
á{$ûÞ♠$%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///wwmqVw7sPz3s0c4GK6v//0UpuRZkpiZVKOkq@@XkQRnhqSl5qMYQdUgpjBSeWlBZBBTNKi2CipWBNsf8B)

### Explanation

```
á{         sort by the output given from a code block
  $        convert to ordinal (base 256)
   ûÞ♠     push "Þ♠"
      $    convert to ordinal (gives 1791)
       %   modulo
```

I had the exact same idea as isaacg's Pyth answer, but in MathGolf I had to use another modulo. I tried every number up to 1000000, and noticed that the ordinal strings for each weekday ended up in the correct order for sorting when taking them modulo 1791.

Comment: Tried to find a shorter way to generate `1791`, but can't find one unfortunately. I did found an equal-bytes alternative, though: `○♠~+` (2048+~256).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I thought about modifying the input string (e.g. "Monday") or its ordinal, in order to change the 1791 into another nicer number (hopefully a 1-byte builtin), but I didn't investigate further there. Best case scenario is that it saves 2 bytes, which would be tied with 05AB1E.

Comment: You mean like removing the first character of the string before the `$` or something along those lines?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yes, something along those lines. It could also be squaring the number after the `$`, or something similar. But there were so many operators to try that I gave up before I started.

Answer (score 3):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org) , 58 bytes

```
DayOfWeek.values().map{it.name.toLowerCase().capitalize()}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>72</s></sup> 70 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to gastropner!!!

```c
f(){puts("Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NQ7O6oLSkWEPJNz8vJbFSIaQ0tRhEh6em5EFYIRmlRWCGW1EmiApOLCktAjNKQTqUNK1r/2fmlSjkJmbmaWgqVHMBzbTmqv0PAA)

Just prints the days of the week.
Unfortunately this is shorter than sorting the input! T_T

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) Little Endian Byte Order, <sup><s>123</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>99</s></sup> 85 bytes

```c
h,s;c(int**a,int**b){h=(h=**a%274%79)>(s=**b%274%79)-(h<s);}f(int*s){qsort(s,7,8,c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZBNS8QwEIbv/RVDoZB0pyBFqNKtR2@eVvCw7iHbD5PDppo0iJT@9pr0g7oVT7vOpSRPZ@bNk0dved73HHWaEyGbMGQ4fI605Rnhmb0I4uQ2SO7pA9H2eJyPEeFbTdOuGvo0bT90rRqiMcE7zC3o7T2cmJCEQut5YCvnTMGplvsDZOA/1bJgX366oMaUI3o2pV6xz7IY2UtZyF@04Wbq5EatYaXECB@VWCHNmhHtWGPUGpop6c6sk4aKyWKfONq6aOgSoNuE7hXoXoluALoV0I2tVa2cLRDZTQpim6Sw2QhnB6Z6VxZXxA/0q/QRhiXiQMfuzvv5S3Re4OyXBayuIztnaq@IG0f/PclftSRZDMazQisJJ4/n9matlyiMr@wwplfK0vXf)

Function `f` takes a list of strings as input and sorts it.

**How**

Reads the first four characters as a 32-bit `int`, \$i\$, and then calculates \$((i\mod{274})\mod{79})\$:

```c
Monday -> 5
Tuesday -> 7
Wednesday -> 11
Thursday -> 23
Friday -> 47
Saturday -> 59
Sunday -> 61
```

Then uses `qsort` to sort the array.

Comment: You could save 2 bytes by using `puts()` instead of `printf()`.

Comment: @gastropner Nice one - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>33</s> 29 bytes

```perl
print+(sort<>)[1,5,6,4,0,2,3]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvRFujOL@oxMZOM9pQx1THTMdEx0DHSMc49v9/t6LMlMRKLt/8PBAVUppaDKYzSovAjODEktIiMKMUrCA8NSUPogQA) Just another sort/permute answer. Edit: Saved 4 bytes thanks to @Xcali.

Comment: Shaved 4 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvRFujOL@oxMZOM9pQx1THTMdAx0THSMc49v9/t6LMlMRKLt/8PBAVUppaDKYzSovAjODEktIiMKMUrCA8NSUPogQA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: @Xcali Thanks! I don't really know Perl, I was just putting in parentheses until it stopped erroring...

Comment: I just found another issue there.  Thursday and Friday are reversed in your output.

Comment: @Xcali Thanks for spotting my typo... (I got the sequence of digits correct in my other answer at least.)

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 39 bytes

```php
for(;$i<7;)echo" ".jddayofweek($i++,1);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxVMm3MrTVTkzPylRSU9LJSUhIr89PKU1OzNVQytbV1DDWt//8HAA)

Works in Windows but not in TIO, gotta find how to activate the extension.. takes no input.

We could save 4 bytes with an empty delimiter (which is "some delimiter" the question doesn't say a **non-empty** delimiter) but I'm not that nasty..

EDIT: version that works universally for 1 byte more

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 40 bytes

```php
for(;$i<7;)echo date("l ",1e6+$i++*8e4);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxVMm3MrTVTkzPyFVISS1I1lHIUlHQMU820VTK1tbUsUk00rf//BwA)

Answer (score 3):

### Powershell, 23 bytes

```
1..6+0|%{[DayOfWeek]$_}
```

Convert integers to weekday, but bump array by one because .net prefers Sundays.

### 37 bytes sorting

```
($args|%{[DayOfWeek]$_}|sort)[1..6+0]
```

input is string list to args.

Comment: [21 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/P9olsdI/LTw1NTs6NlbDUE/PTNtA8/9/AA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 15 bytes

```
“jnsDt[rƳm⑺dQ7⅍
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N////UcOcrLxil5LoomObcx9N3JUSaP6otff/fwA)

You'd think this was some sort of fancy sorting algorithm, but no. It's simply a compressed string.

Comment: Meh, I've got 22 in Jelly: [`“¡²2GỌḌ¹Ẹṙṙ,ßṃþ-wẈÇUx»`](https://tio.run/##ATYAyf9qZWxsef//4oCcwqHCsjJH4buM4biMwrnhurjhuZnhuZksw5/huYPDvi134bqIw4dVeMK7//8 "Jelly – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Unix utilities, 29 bytes

```bash
jot "-wdate +%%A -d7-1-" 7|sh
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Pyu/REFJtzwlsSRVQVtV1VFBN8Vc11BXScG8BiQNAA)

Comment: Nice solution, but it isn't ISO 8601 compliant unfortunately. The week should start with Monday for this challenge.

Comment: Fixed.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 24 bytes

```
print system/locale/days
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhId@7@gKDOvRKG4srgkNVc/Jz85MSdVPyWxsvj/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 10 bytes

```
1314 A./:~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DY0NTRQc9fSt6v5rcilwpSZn5CukKaiHlKYWpyRWqlsrqIenpuTBOb75eVCWW1EmlBWcWFJaBGOXwuRDMkqLwLrgZhKtw5qg/Vz/AQ)

[J](http://jsoftware.com/) Port of [isaacg's alternative Pyth solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204078/43319) — please upvote him!

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 40 bytes

```
^
MTuWThFSaSu
,6L$s`(.+)(?=.*(\1\w+))
$2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPzvb5/wP47LN6Q0PCTDLTgxuJRLx8xHpThBQ09bU8PeVk9LI8YwplxbU5NLxej/f9/8vJTESq6Q0tRiEB2empIHYYVklBaBGW5FmSAqOLGktAjMKAXpAAA) Link shuffles input in header. Explanation:

```
^
MTuWThFSaSu
```

Insert unique day name abbreviations.

```
,6L$s`(.+)(?=.*(\1\w+))
$2
```

Find the first seven duplicate substrings, and output the word containing the duplicate, thus unabbreviating the names.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>29</s> 25 bytes

```
≔Ｅ⁷ＳθＷ⁻θυ⊞υ⌊ιＥ1564023§υＩι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HUy7CsMgFN3zFZLpCunSpUPHUKFDoGAgsyS2SkXN1VvI11vjdN5nNQrXoFwp74AMbpy9KBmggT19pCwzWv8Bzu9dy2V0NkM/hZkWPRuBUknqB3bldVirGYR1WeN58NhJuQTjsTo9mhDhe/YGZnm9K0Wg3dTRTcGfIFUmbISankmnhoawkUVvvlnl8nN/) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔Ｅ⁷Ｓθ
```

Input the seven days.

```
Ｗ⁻θυ⊞υ⌊ι
```

Sort the days lexicographically.

```
Ｅ1564023§υＩι
```

Apply the permutation to the array.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 4 bytes

```
23Y2
```

Built-in ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. Takes no input.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/38g40uj/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>32</s> <s>29</s> <s>27</s> 26 bytes

```
Tu
13
T`MWT`E
O`
T`d`MTWuT
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/pJTL0JgrJME3PCTBlcs/AchMSfANCS8NAcpllBYVpyRWcvnm54GokNJUMDe4FMwNT03Jgwi4FWWCxRNLSouADAA)

**Approach**: <s>Replace the first letter of the days with `A`, `B`, `C`, etc. so we can sort them lexicographically.</s> Replace the `M` in Monday with a `0`, the `T` in Tuesday with a `1`, the `W` in Wednesday with a `2`, and the `T` in Thursday with `4`. To help golf off a byte, also replace the `u` in Tuesday with `3`

```
Tu
13
T`MWT`E
```

Perform the replacements described above (The `E` inserts even numbers `02468`)

```
O`
```

Sort lexicographically. At this point, our list of words looks like this:

```
0onday
13esday
2ednesday
4hursday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday
```

Notice that Friday, Saturday, and Sunday are already conveniently in alphabetical order.

```
T`d`MTWuT
```

Undo the transformations we performed above (The `d` inserts the range `0-9`)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
n á g#4
```

[Try it here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=biDhIGcjgzQ&input=WyJGcmlkYXkiLCJNb25kYXkiLCJXZWRuZXNkYXkiLCJUdWVzZGF5IiwiU2F0dXJkYXkiLCJUaHVyc2RheSIsIlN1bmRheSJd)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>64</s> <s>62</s> 59 chars

Takes input as a list of strings, sorts it inplace:

```
lambda l:l.sort(key=lambda x:'uehrau'.find(x[1],x[0]=='S'))
```

Try it:   https://ideone.com/rYxtff

Answer (score 2):

## R (English locale), 36 bytes

```
weekdays(.leap.seconds[c(8:12,6:7)])
```

Not quite as short as the other answer, but I posted it because it makes use of one of the strangest objects kicking around in base R — a list of all the leap seconds. It so happens that leap seconds frequently occur in increasing sequences of days so we only have to take two "chunks" from the list.

Luckily, the leap seconds object has the oldest leap second first, so I don't have to qualify this program with "will only work for the next 2–3 years"!

TIO link [here](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzw1NTslsbJYQy8nNbFArzg1OT8vpTg6WcPCytBIx8zKXDNW8/9/AA).

Comment: This is certainly one of the most interesting approaches. I've never coded in R, but you could add a TIO link, [something like this](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzw1NTslsbJYQy8nNbFArzg1OT8vpTg6WcPCytBIx8zKXDNW8/9/AA).

Comment: Thanks — I used your link to edit my answer — hope that's alright!

Comment: Well I used your code in my link, so I guess we're even.

Answer (score 1):

**Python**

Input: Space separated strings

Once the input is sorted then the output should be ordered using indices [1, 5, 6, 4, 0, 2, 3] of the sorted array

```
inp=sorted(input().split())
for i in [1, 5, 6, 4, 0, 2, 3]:
  print(inp[i])
```

Try it [here](https://tio.run/##JYsxC8IwFAb3/opvbOAhalVEcHVzsuBQOhQS6QN5CS/J0F8fGzvdcXBhSbOX7hq0FJZwj16Ts@2qObVmF8OXV5rm4xUMFgwHwplwIZwIe8KR0I23BgjKkuo48GhK6bOLdlrw9FLxdla28Mr/8FCu6OesW55S1lV@)

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! While it is a good answer, I'll suggest some general code golf optimizations: make all variables 1 byte, and remove all unnecessary whitespace. With those optimizations, your code becomes [14 bytes shorter](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P9G2OL@oJDVFIzOvoLREQ1OvuCAnE0hrcqXlFylkKmTmRRvqmOqY6ZjoGOgY6RjHWhUUZeaVaCRGZ8Zq/v8fUppanJJYqeCbnweiwlNT8iACwaVgAbeiTBAVklFaBBFOLCktAjIA).

Answer (score 1):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 464 bytes

```
{{i}dd}dddc{i}{i}{i}iiiicdc{d}cdddc{i}{i}iiiic{{d}}{d}dc{{i}ddd}iiiic{i}{i}{i}iiic{d}ddddddc{i}iiiic{d}dddddcdddc{i}{i}iiiic{{d}}{d}dc{{i}dd}dddc{i}iiiicdc{i}c{d}ic{i}iiiic{d}dddddcdddc{i}{i}iiiic{{d}}{d}dc{{i}ddd}iiiic{i}{i}c{i}iiicdddcic{d}dddddcdddc{i}{i}iiiic{{d}}{d}dc{{i}dddd}c{{i}dddddd}iiiic{d}icdddddcdddc{i}{i}iiiic{{d}}{d}dc{{i}ddd}iiic{i}iiiic{i}{i}dcicdddc{d}ddddcdddc{i}{i}iiiic{{d}}{d}dc{{i}ddd}iiic{i}{i}{i}iiiic{d}iiic{d}cdddc{i}{i}iiiic{{d}}{d}dc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZBLDoAwCERP5KEMo5G1y4azI9CvC2NLaEInfdNpcew4@b421ZRYAGuQTbnZimwPoa6HmEwTWyYGhyIPpGOIokYV5c9NRigmR3nZ55Wq0MEsWNjb69T8PMt8gB47DvrtgeUE0xbjGdQP/qZVHw)

Deadfish - the worst compression algorithm.