# Consecutive coin flips

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, combinatorics

*This is a cross-post of a problem I posted to anarchy golf: http://golf.shinh.org/p.rb?tails*

Given two integers \$ n \$ and \$ k \$ \$ (0 \le k \le n) \$, count the number of combinations of \$ n \$ coin tosses with at least \$ k \$ tails in a row.

For example, if \$ n = 3 \$ and \$ k = 2 \$, the answer is \$ 3 \$:

```
HHH ❌
HHT ❌
HTH ❌
HTT ✔️
THH ❌
THT ❌
TTH ✔️
TTT ✔️
```

**For convenience sake, you do not need to handle the case where \$ n = k = 0 \$**.

### Rules

- The input must take in two integers \$ n \$ and \$ k \$, and output the answer as a single integer
- Inaccuracies due to integer overflow are acceptable, but floating point errors are prohibited
- As usual for [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code in bytes wins

### Test Cases

```
 n,  k  ->  ans
---------------
 1,  0  ->  2
 1,  1  ->  1
 2,  0  ->  4
 2,  1  ->  3
 2,  2  ->  1
 3,  1  ->  7
 3,  2  ->  3
 3,  3  ->  1
 5,  2  ->  19
 6,  4  ->  8
 9,  2  ->  423
12,  0  ->  4096
13,  5  ->  1262
14,  8  ->  256
16,  7  ->  2811
```

More terms are listed under [OEIS A109435](https://oeis.org/A109435).

Comment: "For example, if n=3 and k=2, the answer is 2:" but you then go on to quote the correct value of 3 in your test cases.

Comment: @Neil Fixed, thanks. I changed the example case last minute and forgot to update the answer as well..

Answer (score 12):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 50 bytes

```
lambda n,k:sum(k*"1"in bin(i)for i in range(2**n))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3jXISc5NSEhXydLKtiktzNbK1lAyVMvMUkjLzNDI10_KLFDIVgNyixLz0VA0jLa08TU2oTnuQZB5C0tBA04pLoaAoM69EQ0sjTak6TSNPRyFb08q4VkkBpDYbodZUE2bMggUQGgA)

Brute-force solution seems to be the shortest.

---

### [Python](https://www.python.org), 67 bytes

```
lambda n,k:2**n-(g:=lambda a:a*k>0and(a<3or g(a-1)*2-g(a+~k)))(n+2)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3nXMSc5NSEhXydLKtjLS08nQ10q1soWKJVola2XYGiXkpGok2xvlFCukaibqGmlpGukCGdl22pqamRp62kSbUKPs0oJI8hcw8haLEvPRUDUMDTSsuhYKizLwSDS2NNKXqNI08HYVsTSvjWiUFkNpshFpToFkQYxYsgNAA)

-11 bytes thanks to Neil.

More mathematical answer.

$$
f(n, k) = 2^n - k \operatorname{-bonacci}(n+k)
\\
k \operatorname{-bonacci}(n) =
\begin{cases}
0 & n < k-1 \\
1 & n = k-1 \\
\sum^k_{i=1} k \operatorname{-bonacci}(n-i) & n > k-1
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: `lambda n,k:2**n-(g:=lambda a:a*k>0and(a<3or g(a-1)*2-g(a+~k)))(n+2)` saves 11 bytes and should be much faster.

Answer (score 8):

## x86-64 machine code, 28 bytes

```
31 C0 99 52 89 F1 FF C9 78 07 D1 EA 72 F8 75 F4 41 FF C0 5A FF C2 0F A3 FA 73 E8 C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVLBctMwED1rv2IbJjMStjtJyHBwai6cuXBihnBwJDnekMjBcsChza/j7iYtDTPcqsNKu9J7@54km62tHYYy7lB/HmmoctU3LfqyTyWAsu4HlLnaH2KNrethlatd8xO9lQORwObKeSs5qE1EByrWjHe8PeWKRcsx/MYVqNvVsfM46edTcLmiYC8d9s3@zHypyGLVXQi8IwFbLEG1vgMzMgug0GGlJYYUZfrORXjD4O3BebyLnaPmtv5wPrgrKWgD99yl5bzSI8QHYVEVuzyzbLDAyYKnmwKnM14kiQG8Gn@R4zmNUtwI@rm2DFmWZK8Y/2qhixZ61kKiRbH6q4bjGT2wDBLgf1zcFUhPJtQL7Ek731u6MYI8gbp2sQyfSltT8Ggb5/OzKqHthTbFI6euwfsXusnsC/MdC60PIdI6eIe2Ltu3pjJf@yT5ZhYn/FXT1qM@iptJ//Hd9cWhHhPKf4hmGZipl01@40Mb2AechuGPrbblOg7Z7v2cA//QgqF@@wg)

Following the standard calling convention for Unix-like systems (from the System V AMD64 ABI), this takes n in EDI and k in ESI and returns the answer in EAX.

In assembly:

```
f:  xor eax, eax
    cdq
a:  push rdx
b:  mov ecx, esi
c:  dec ecx
    js d
    shr edx, 1
    jc c
    jnz b
    .byte 0x41
d:  inc eax
    pop rdx
    inc edx
    bt edx, edi
    jnc a
    ret
```

Comment: +1 for skipping `inc` with `0x41`.

Answer (score 7):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, <s>13</s> <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
EƛbĠṠ⁰≥a
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzIiwiIiwiRcabYsSg4bmg4oGw4omlYSIsIiIsIjFcbjAiXQ==)

A very neat little answer I'm very happy with.

### Explained

```
EƛbĠṠ⁰≥a
Eƛ       # to each item in the range [1, 2 ** N)
  bĠṠ    #   get the sums of consecutive digits of the binary representation of that number
     ⁰≥a #   are any of those greater than K? This is essentially getting all consecutive runs of flips and getting there length. Works because there's only 1s and 0s
# the s flag sums that list.
```

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES7), 59 bytes

Expects `(n)(k)`.

Fully bitwise because binary string manipulation in JS is too verbose.

```javascript
(n,i=1<<n)=>g=k=>i--&&(h=m=>i&m^m?h(m*2):m<=i)(2**k-1)+g(k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc9NDoIwEAXgvafoisygCB1@FEPxJiYEBSq0GDFeH1lAIBV2Tb6896bP7Jt1@Vu@Po5u74@@ED3ogxQ8STSKtBS1SKXjWBZUQg1PS93UtQJlE15UIiQC2XbtcNyXUGOft7prm8exaUsogHEED5G5LmO0@zc@GjeN5lywYlPOXzHa6vTn3GnFaKtzMH@rM1zsxSZGCMGIZ9PiORiQOcmX3/fiyOThonBapYj6Hw)

---

## JavaScript (ES7), 38 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Neil*

Expects `(k)(n)`. Returns [*true* for *1*](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9067/58563).

Uses [loopy walt's recursion formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248518/58563).

```javascript
k=>g=n=>n>k?2*g(--n)-g(n-=k)+2**n:n==k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ddFLDoMgEIDhvadgCRqqAz6bYM9irJIWA01ten3KQoxBuv7yk5nhOXyHdXw/Xh@qzX2ys7BK9FJo0ete3VgqMaWaUIk1FYpkLE31VQuh7Gj0apbpshiJsxkXBCMgBOU5QiwJEA4ISaRkG5ax0iMPkR0QYiXfsImV/N@z/IAQKyuPXail03rTNpZ2flHGI3eA/Q5FV4deOd/HYvXpyK3z0v9Adcobx3401gLYHw)

Comment: Having only just finished golfing @pxeger's Python answer it would have been 53 bytes in ES7: `k=>n=>2**n-(g=a=>a*k>0&&(a<3||g(a-1)*2-g(a+~k)))(n+2)`

Comment: `k=>g=n=>n-k?n>k&&2*g(--n)-g(n-=k)+2**n:1` saves 2 bytes, although it requires ES7.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 55 bytes

```
f=lambda n,k:n>=k and 2*f(n-1,k)-(-1<<n>>-~k)-f(n+~k,k)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3zdNscxJzk1ISFfJ0sq3y7GyzFRLzUhSMtNI08nQNdbI1dTV0DW1s8uzsdOuAHKCodl02UBiq3SEtv0ghTyEzT6EoMS89VcPIQNOKS6GgKDOvRENLI02pGqhBRyFb08qsVkkBpDYbRa0m1ByYcwA)

Slightly longer than [@pxeger's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248500/107561) but more efficient.

#### How?

Uses the recurrence

\$f(n,k)=2f(n-1,k)+2^{n-k-1}-f(n-k-1,k)\qquad(n>k)\$

which is obtained by counting words that have k consecutive 1's somewhere in the first n-1 places, words that end in a 0 followed by k 1's and the overlap of these two groups.

Answer (score 5):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 40 bytes

```
k->g(n,r=k)=if(!r,2^n,n,g(n--,r--)+g(n))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Nc5BCsIwEEDRq0RXGZwBk7S1LtqLlCjZpJRKCKEuvIngpiDimbyNSdNu8uaHBOb19SYM197Pb8uaz32yVP_4SG3PHYZmhGawfBdQXhw6jJdEGIjgEEeA9f3TeH97cMOoZT4MborjPsWeWW46qSGeQgMg6zqBRx0VKBIyl9xKJlQutZVKlLkqLBLnXGL9LxSWiwXWixWetF73m-fsHw)

A port of [@tsh's JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248536/9288).

---

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 42 bytes

```
k->n->(y=1-x)/(y-=x)/(x+y/x^k)%x^(n+1)\x^n
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Nc5BCoMwEEDRqwShkNQEO4lau9CL2FiysYgSglhIblLoRiilZ-ptaoxu5s1fDMzra9TY3e5mfreo_DymlhW_Y88qzSrsSmCWJNix0mNjl9imJwfbYB0DudpGbxdPZczgsEKsQmbs9LSskY8ItVjVXJJlgiSEoroGepKLQMHDQ_G9uEeEEnsJTxYqp6nnEgq2exA0W01psZrTs5Qk_DfPwT8)

According to OEIS, the generating function for column \$k\$ is \$\frac{x^k}{(1-\sum_{i=1}^k x^i)(1-2x)}\$, which could be simplified to \$\frac{(1-x)}{(1-2x)(x+(1-2x)/x^k)}\$.

Comment: nice use of generating functions

Answer (score 5):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>21</s> 19 bytes

-2 bytes saved thanks to a suggestion by [coltim](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98547/coltim) on another answer.

Enumerates all binary length-n sequences and counts the ones with runs of at least k 1s.

```
{+/y<|/1(1+*)\!x#2}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJw1jjESgzAMBHu/ggwNCQVIso2N+AnQ8oYwJHl77DPu9k6rkY756odz+QzUUf96bo93y19jzLGSjnvzaxhIGSkhl9YC0QqQqyClnYBcBVGpgrvdmNirzRwSxlJbzjrVM2P0OYo67LDHO1YDXnMYep2QAtEfipkyPg==)

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `sequences.repeating`, 58 bytes

```factor
[ "1"swap cycle swap 2^ iota [ >bin subseq? ] with count ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZFBSwMxEIXv@RXP3l2a7HbbVViP4sWLeCoV0jDVYJtdkyyllP72Na3EzWpDCOGbN2@SmY1UvrH968vT8@MdPska2sLRV0dGkcsstSS9Nu/YSf9xObJWWkd2EEE61yiH1pL3h9Zq43HP2JEhrCPAgSlOwA1ua0AkmA@YRyxG6iLBiTpPsLhiko/U8wSLKyb5ef83mY29q8jL8KyBLyKuRvJCRHv@50fTqoyR/FxkqCDK2BxeBOOkZ7PflFB8ngQWnLMT65eY8InbyxbqoLaEy1W8QTdeYol6rQ1ctw4je8AKex1GqZouzGnVb37GV@9CRtZ/Aw)

---

Longer but much cooler:

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 67 bytes

```factor
[| n k | n 2^ ""n [ dup k short tail* sum suffix ] times last - ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZHBS8MwFMbZNX/F547CZEm7blXYVbx4EU9jQqgpK0vTmryCMve31xSJTd1CksPvfe97yXulLKix/evL0/PjPXRTSO1QSzrgqKxRGk59dMoUykE61xQOrVVEX62tDOGBsRODXyeAA0ucgRsstoCIMB8xD1hM1GmEI3USYXHFJJmo1xEWV0ySYV@arKbeeeCZf9bINwHnE3kqgj3/96NlnoVIMhQZK4gsNIen3jjq2eovxRdfR4EN5@zM@t03DI4YbvGG@Ww2N9jhvWs9dIfGEkhW@hauq/0py@oTe1BV@@Fp6QgL7Pvyd47bWra4638A)

\$2^n\$ minus the \$(n+k-1)\$th k-bonacci number.

Example:

\$n=6, k=4\$

The tetranacci sequence begins:
\$0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 15, 29, \color{red}{56}\$

\$2^6-56=8\$

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
1xẇⱮSɓ2ṗ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9@w4uGu9kcb1wWfnGz0cOf0/4eXO@hrRv7/H22oYxCrAyQNgaQRmG0EZRsBSWMw2xjKNgaSpmC2mY4JkLQEsw0h2gyNdUxBlImOBYgy0zGPBQA)

\$k\$ on the left, \$n\$ on the right.

```
   Ɱ        For each
     ɓ2ṗ    sequence of n 1s and 2s,
  ẇ         does it contain as a sublist
1x          k 1s?
    S       Sum.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>89</s></sup> 88 bytes

```c
m;r;a;b;c;f(n,k){for(c=b=1<<n;b--;c-=m<k)for(a=b,m=r=0;a;m=r>m?r:m)r+=a&1?:-r,a/=2;m=c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZJvb4IwEMbf71NcTFxAS6SIf0v1xbJPMc0CtTjDqKaQjIzw1ceOSo0uI@W4Pk/vl@sF4R2FaNucaRazhAmWOopkbp2etSN4wmkUKZZ4HhMez6PM7fSYJyTnmvtYgt9NvtXr3NVjHj/T7drTJJ7wAB3BmvakSsjjk3JcqJ8An04oZVG@q7c9cBRqSgBXYNfUrhmBOYEVuqhSFGiI77xhj5zMcnzD8S2NWhrG0ETfMJcEFncMWV2kKOXBUOprXWjqMFnYhK5MYRjgNvRX866pedfvDNNgSWlPFGdVlCA@Yj3CKEUm9RU82FWvwa5aveA7GxC4308HfTUOF5yuqZM6yArLfNanERSnb3lOHduuO@mF0U1hMB6b066BXcdtr6mQ1o/dnNmzBzuzdvavXaDd/RiQuY@GROM2wb@VF41HUmcwPBAYHsDbdHFY7BTev2MRKMhtSgXnct/Tm6em/RHpZ3wsWu/rFw)

*Saved a byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!*

Answer (score 4):

**C** (standard compliant), 78 bytes

`int f(int n,int k,int c){return n?n+c-k?k-c?f(n-1,k,0)+f(n-1,k,c+1):1<<n:1:0;}`

For the readable version:

```
int f(int n,int k,int c){
    if(n==0)return 0; // no more coin flip left => no possible path
    if(n==(k-c))return 1; // last coin flip and 1 tail is lacking
    if(k==c)return 1<<n; // we have done k tails in a row, any path is a good path, and there are 2^n
    return f(n-1,k,0) // possible paths if we get a head
    +f(n-1,k,c+1); // possible paths if we get a tail
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in C](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2203/tips-for-golfing-in-c) page for ways you can golf your program. You might also want to link an online interprter like [Try It Online](https://tio.run/##NczRCsIgFMbx@z3FYREoaijRjZN8ljjOEusszF2NPbu1QTc//nwXH6o7YjskwuccRvepIU2nx7UlqhDZJsnNvIt8KWOdCwF5Eqiyzwp9ZKSMzFJz8U8UhlvjHFlj9bDud69bIsZh6QDe5TdE1h9DLyMzZwkXCZrzoVvbFw) so people can test your code.

Comment: Welcome also from me. You can sometimes (usually) save some bytes by dropping the ```return``` keyword and relying on the hacky property of C functions to return the last assignment, and save some more by skipping declaring ```int```s (which is default) [like this](https://tio.run/##NYtBCsIwEADvfcVSEbIkkQTxkkbzFtkYDbGrtPVU@vYYBG/DDEP6TlR3men5iTc/LzG/Do9LzbxAEqyKIlzpzIEl6RKKptC0ti0YlH8kadFZ79lZZ4btd4/XzAJh7QDeUxNJ9PvYqyTsUcFJgUEcuq1@AQ)... (although both of these would probably counteract the 'standard compliant' aspect...)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 28 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
{1⊥⍵≤⌈/∘(≢¨⊆⍨)⍤1⍉(⍺⍴2)⊤⍳2*⍺}
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=ATsAxP97MeKKpeKNteKJpOKMiC/iiJgo4omiwqjiiobijagp4o2kMeKNiSjijbrijbQyKeKKpOKNszIq4o26fQ&f=e9Q39VHbBEMThTQFC65HYI4lkG0EZZuC2AA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

Alternatively (same length): `{1⊥(∨/(⍵⍴1)⍷⊢)⍤1⍉(⍺⍴2)⊤⍳2*⍺}`

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 39 bytes

```
.+,(.+)
<$1*1>
"$+"+%`$
0$"1
<(.*)>.*\1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X09bR0NPW5PLRsVQy9COS0lFW0lbNUGFy0BFyZDLRkNPS9NOTysGqNBUxwgA) No test suite due to the way the program uses history. Explanation:

```
.+,(.+)
<$1*1>
```

Replace the input with a string of `k` `1`s wrapped in `<>`s.

```
"$+"+
```

Repeat `n` times.

```
%`$
0$"1
```

Duplicate each row, appending `0` and `1` to each copy respectively.

```
<(.*)>.*\1
```

Count the number of rows where the binary portion contains `k` `1`s.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>72</s> 68 bytes

*Edit: -4 bytes thanks to @Dominic van Essen.*

```
\(n,k)sum(sapply(1:2^n-1,\(x,r=rle(intToBits(x)>0))any(r$l*r$v>=k)))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VdDPCoIwHAdwuvoKXQZ52ELB_VFnoIfoETpK4CFBNJOpoc_SxYIeqp4ml03cafDh-_vut90fYnim4attUpu_DzEsrRzV7QXWSVUVPcQ7ciptbMWws0QoijPMyuZ43WdNDTsUOQglZQ-FWWyFeYvCHCE0dX1Wa5BCbAHgoA0AdgQAMf6ClWApZJlhSuYMVUK0KbrM-EqINiWFalOu1hNI8kZiiriUYBlihBrj1vqSTuBJlP3u3EY8IpGNyOcnu7-gvMOfjWM8_dEwTOcX)

Comment: [68 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VdDPCoIwHAdwuvoKXQZ52ELB_VFnoIfoETpK4CFBNJOpoc_SxYIeqp4ml03cafDh-_vut90fYnim4attUpu_DzEsrRzV7QXWSVUVPcQ7ciptbMWws0QoijPMyuZ43WdNDTsUOQglZQ-FWWyFeYvCHCE0dX1Wa5BCbAHgoA0AdgQAMf6ClWApZJlhSuYMVUK0KbrM-EqINiWFalOu1hNI8kZiiriUYBlihBrj1vqSTuBJlP3u3EY8IpGNyOcnu7-gvMOfjWM8_dEwTOcX)...

Comment: Ah, that's the fix for k=1 I was looking for. Thanks, @DominicvanEssen!

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 94 bytes

```
.+,(.+)
1$&$*0;$&$*11;$1$*,1,
+`1;1*,(((1)|,)*)
;$1$#3$*1,
+`^(1+)0
$1$1
r`\2;;(1*,)*(1*),$

1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcoxDsIwFAPQ3dcgoP@Tr6pO2gLKAbgEQmVgYGGoGLl7@OniJ9neXt/359mOclvbkEyGpGA4hTjWnmQNDNFoSCsro4kI9WcaFX06FD/18SFMOsIrYlvvuVbxt0ZPtQCwNdoIGpHdvJtR3LJbMLuLTbi67CcWm8HJLuBi5z8) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
.+,(.+)
1$&$*0;$&$*11;$1$*,1,
```

Create `2ⁿ` in binary, `n+1` in unary, then a list of `k` `0`s and a `1`.

```
+`1;1*,(((1)|,)*)
;$1$#3$*1,
```

Repeat `n+1` times, drop the first element of the list, and append the sum of the remaining elements. This calculates the `n+1`th k-bonacci number.

```
+`^(1+)0
$1$1
```

Convert the `2ⁿ` from binary into unary.

```
   r`\2;;(1*,)*(1*),$
```

Subtract the `n+1`th k-bonacci number from `2ⁿ`.

```
1
```

Convert to decimal.

Rather than trying to count the number of `n` coin tosses with at least `k` tails in a row, it's easier to consider the number of `n` coin tosses that do not have `k` tails in a row. By considering them grouped by the number of tails that they end with, it's possible to determine a recurrence relation for the number of rows. For example, with `k=3`:

- For `0` coin tosses, `1` ends in `0` tails, `0` end in `1` tails, and `0` end in `2` tails. Total `1` matching row.
- For `1` coin toss, `1` ends in `0` tails, `1` ends in `1` tails, and `0` end in `2` tails. Total `2` matching rows.
- For `2` coin tosses, `2` end in `0` tails, `1` ends in `1` tails, and `1` ends in `2` tails. Total `4` matching rows.
- For `3` coin tosses, `4` end in `0` tails, `2` end in `1` tails, and `1` ends in `2` tails. Total `7` matching rows.
- For `4` coin tosses, `7` end in `0` tails, `4` end in `1` tails, and `2` end in `2` tails. Total `13` matching rows.
- For `n` coin tosses:

  - The number that end in `0` tails is the total for `n-1` coin tosses, since the value is simply that plus an extra toss of heads.
  - The number that end in `1` tails is the number that end in `0` tails for `n-1` coin tosses, with each row having an extra toss of tails. However, this is also the total for `n-2` coin tosses.
  - The number that end in `2` tails is the number that end in `1` tails for `n-1` coin tosses, with each row having an extra toss of tails. Recursively, we see that this is also the total for `n-3` coin tosses.
  - The total is the sum of these which is also the total of the previous three totals. Thus, this forms a `3`-binacci sequence.

In general, the number of `n` coin tosses that do not have `k` tails in a row is a `k`-binacci sequence.

The number of `n` coin tosses with at least `k` tails in a row plus the number of `n` coin tosses that do not have `k` tails in a row is of course the total possible number of rows, `2ⁿ`.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
TIã$×δåO
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/xPPwYpXD089tObzU//9/Yy4jAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVCaNj/kMjDiw0jDk8/t@XwUv//Ov@jow11DGJ1gKQhkDQCs42gbCMgaQxmG0PZxkDSFMw20zEBkpZgtiFEm6GxjimIMtGxAFFmOuaxsQA) or [try it step-by-step](https://tio.run/##RY9BSgQxEEX3c4pP47IHzLgTZBaCMCtl9AKZdI0pujtpUgmCF/EA4g28wey9UludcXATqur/9yBR7IFpnpunIh7m@hbN9uVudV6zJxw5SQaHqWSEJd1pem9TJmEbMKXYFZeX4PR54Qxs6Cot5KKOZ7xfWo1p9b3S6p4msrnWDHrYMZaQEY/IPJLACiQnDq/V/aHAQ0wg6/zfXa0VJpsGpoSBJbdwnlwPVotnQb8WfqcOZn1hVAwph3/1z/fpS@XPZWzx5ln12oklIZGUof7scTvPN6vNLw).

**Explanation:**

```python
T        # Push 10
 I       # Push the first input `n`
  ã      # Take the cartesian product of the two, to create all possible n-sized strings
         # containing 0s and 1s
   $     # Push 1 and the second input `k`
    ×    # Repeat the 1 `k` amount of times as string
     δ   # Map over the list we created earlier, using this "1"-string as argument:
      å  #  Check if the "1"-string is a substring of the string we're mapping over
       O # Sum to get the amount of truthy values
         # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 14 bytes

```
0<1XbNTB_MS,Ea
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSboFS7IKlpSVpuhbrDGwMI5L8QpzifYN1XBMhglC5ZdGWOgpGMJUA)

Brute force, same concept as pxeger's Python answer.

-5 bytes thanks to DLosc

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 39 bytes

```javascript
k=>g=(n,r=k)=>r?n&&g(--n,--r)+g(n):2**n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ddBNDoMgEAXgvadgZcBKFfC3CfYsxippNdBg0@tTFtJYoSsW33uTYR79u18HfX@@sFS30UzczLwTHMpU8xnxTl9lHAuIsUwx1ugkoEQXmiTSDEquahnPixJwgjmCgCAEsgwAGv0a2RmJ/B7drAj0nLGD0Z2RQI9tVgd67M9MtjMS6JXO2gMWFqsNm0CxdR@kLLKvdwHyvUDeVn6itInvXrSifqKxicJdvwyMqG3AbUgbQswH)

```javascript
k=>    // Number of tails required in a row
g=(
  n,   // Number of coins we will flip
  r=k  // Number of tails still required in a row
)=>
  r?   // Do we still require tails?
   n&& // And we have more coins can flip?
    g(--n,--r)+ // Luckily, tail this time
    g(n):       // Nope, head this time
  2**n // We don't care what we get from remaining coins
```

Answer (score 3):

## BQN, 20 bytes

```
{+´⥊∨´¨∧´˘¨⊸↕¨↕⥊2}
```

-1 byte thanks to @Razetime!

[Try it here!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgeyvCtOKliuKIqMK0wqjiiKfCtMuYwqjwnZWp4oq44oaVwqjihpXwnZWo4qWKMn0KCijigKJTaG93IEbCtCnCqCDin6gKIDHigL8wCiAx4oC/MQogMuKAvzAKIDLigL8xCiAy4oC/MgogM+KAvzEKIDPigL8yCiAz4oC/MwogNeKAvzIKIDbigL80CiA54oC/MgoxMuKAvzAKMTPigL81CjE04oC/OAoxNuKAvzcK4p+pCkA=)

### Explanation

- `↕⥊2` generate binary sequences of length *n*
- `⊸↕¨` convert each binary sequence to subsequences of length *k*

  - example: `1010` with *k*=3 becomes `101, 010`
- `∨´¨∧´˘¨` AND each subsequence, then OR each result
- `+´⥊` sum to get total number of 1s

Comment: `2¨↕` → `⥊2`

Answer (score 2):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 36 bytes

```
s11rzjCBg1{{gw:pd{-]g1>=}fl}fl}qL[IE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7LCsIwEEX38xXzA4XeSdOHYBeKC8G9C3Ej1oJ00QelYOi3x7QNUcjmcO69mcfYN9XQjZU1JmbMw9RWdgD6z/t4qGFMPe3ap4nuNcr9/GqW111u55Odr41lMMfMUckstAA2ALEEk6zgjVpBQkwFk60gIeZAhZj@dQri1I1ulBMXQSWiCH//xkVKcBvaNyUVgivm/mLttJvKPObAFw)

```
s1     # Save k
1rz    # [0, 1]
jCB    # Combinations up to n
g1     # Get k
{      # Catch k == 0
 {gw   # Group with length ([1, 1, 0] -> [[2, 1], [1, 0]])
  :pd  # Filter for tails
  {    # Filter
   -]  # Head
   g1  # k
   >=  # Greater than or equal
  }
  fl   # Count matches
 }
 fl    # Count matches
}
qL[    # Length of combinations (when k == 0)
IE     # If else
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 15 bytes

```
ＮθＩＬΦＸ²Ｎ№⍘ι²×θ1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05oroCgzr0TDObG4RMMnNS@9JEPDLTOnBCgZkF8OJI10FJB1aGrqKDjnlwJ1OCUWpwaXADWna2TqKBgBxUMyc1OLNQp1FJQMlTTBwPr/fyMF0/@6ZTkA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes `k` as the first input and `n` as the second input. Explanation: Uses brute force, so takes exponential time in `n`.

```
Ｎθ              Input `k` as an integer
      ²         Literal integer `2`
     Ｘ          Raised to power
       Ｎ        Input `n` as an integer
    Φ           Filtered where
          ι     Current value
         ⍘      Converted to base
           ²    Literal integer `2`
        №       Count i.e. contains
              1 Literal string `1`
            ×   Repeated by
             θ  Input `k`
   Ｌ            Take the length
  Ｉ             Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

27 bytes for an efficient version (approximately linear time):

```
ＮθＮη⊞υ¹Ｆ⊕θ⊞υ↨¹✂⮌υ⁰η¹Ｉ⁻Ｘ²θ⊟υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY29DgIhEIR7n2LLJcFELLSw0@oKDdEnQFwDyR3c8XM@Pi6Fid3M5JsZ60yy0YytDWGu5VanJyVcxGnz7x17XbPDKkGxfscEOASbaKJQ6MUFAT/gbDKhkvAYvSW800qJgyok7CS4PiD6XPKh4MXkglcfakYdP/y0l7AwqePMjQ62pg5wbNt1/AI) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes `n` as the first input and `k` as the second input. Explanation:

```
ＮθＮη
```

Input `n` and `k`.

```
⊞υ¹
```

Start with the zeroth term of the k-bonacci sequence.

```
Ｆ⊕θ⊞υ↨¹✂⮌υ⁰η¹
```

Calculate `n+1` additional terms.

```
Ｉ⁻Ｘ²θ⊟υ
```

Subtract the `n+1`th term from `2ⁿ`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pl`, 35 bytes

```perl
$b=<>;$_=grep/T{$b}/,glob"{H,T}"x$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lydbGzlol3ja9KLVAP6RaJalWXyc9Jz9JqdpDJ6RWqUIl/v9/Uy6jf/kFJZn5ecX/dQty/uv6muoZGBoAAA)

Comment: [33 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19fQd9aJd42vSi1QD@kWkW9Vl8nPSc/SanaQyekVqlCJeH/f1MFo3/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULcv7r@prqGRgaAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATLAB](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 71 bytes

```matlab
function f(n,k),sum(contains(string(dec2bin(0:2^n-1)),repmat('1',1,k)))
```

The binary representation of all numbers from 0-2^n-1 will give each combination of coin flips. From that, I can search the resulting string vector for repeated instances of 1 ( my choice for tails) that are at least k long and sum the logical array for the result.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcvBCoAgDADQX@nmBgvSYx8TmGmMcIaufn/17q8ljW82K48k5SZTAaELaTwVUhONLAOGdpYTjpzCzgLLGjaZPSL1fNeo4Lwj/y9Esw8)

Comment: Not sure if `'1'(1+~(1:k))` works in MATLAB (it does in Octave). Also can this be an anonymous function, I think?

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 49 bytes

```
=COUNT(FIND(REPT(1,B2),BASE(SEQUENCE(2^A2)-1,2)))
```

Input for *n* is in `A2` and *k* is in `B2`.

- `SEQUENCE(2^A2)-1` creates an array from 0 to (2^n)-1.
- `BASE(~,2))` converts that array to binary.
- `REPT(1,B2)` creates a string of *k* 1s.
- `FIND(REPT(~),BASE(~))` tries to find that repeated string in each binary element in the array. This returns an array of integers (if it's found in that element) and errors (if it's not).
- `COUNT(FIND(~))` counts the numbers in that array.

[image: Screenshot]