# Weighted coin flip strings

Tags: code-golf, math, probability-theory

Given n, k, and p, find the probability that a weighted coin with probability p of heads will flip heads at least k times in a row in n flips, correct to 3 decimal digits after decimal point (changed from 8 because I don't know how to estimate the accuracy of double computation for this (was using arbitrary precision floating points before)).

Edits:

Examples:

```
n, k, p     -> Output
10, 3, 0.5  -> 0.5078125
100, 6, 0.6 -> 0.87262307
100, 9, 0.2 -> 0.00003779
```

Comment: That's a terse description for sure, but the task is actually pretty clear IMO.

Comment: @Arnauld I haven't voted to close, for the same reason as you mentioned: the challenge is clear. It's just a bit lacking in challenge rules, examples, and especially test cases.

Comment: Are we guaranteed that `k` isn't greater than `n`?

Comment: @xnor output 0 if k is greater, k and n are guaranteed to be at least 0

Comment: Not a bad first challenge, though I'd recommend checking out the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=active) in the future, especially for more complex challenges. It's not a perfect system, but it'll help you catch small mistakes / ambiguities before posting to main. Welcome to the site :-)

Comment: Do we need to handle the case \$p=k=0\$? In that case most of the existing formulas contain \$p^k=0^0\$.

Comment: 0^0 = 1 by default

Comment: @dancxviii Not by default per se. \$n^0=1\$ and \$0^n=0\$, so \$0^0\$ conflicts and is usually undefined. But if we would assume \$0^0=1\$, a lot of things fall into place nicely in mathematics: [see this Wikipedia page for details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>40</s> <s>39</s> <s>18</s> 17 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

**Brute-force approach:**

```
0Lα1Ý²ãʒγOà³@}èPO
```

Byte-count more than halved by porting [*@JonathanAllan*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249352/52210), which uses a similar approach as [@DominicVanEssen's top R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249333/52210), so make sure to upvote them as well!

Inputs in the order \$p,n,k\$.
Very slow, so use small \$n\$ in order to run it on TIO.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fwOfcRsPDcw9tOrz41KRzm/0PLzi02aH28IoAf6CcnimXoQGXMQA)

**Original mathematical <s>40</s> 39 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) approach:**

```
÷L®s©>m²®¹*-D>®/$-*I+s®<cI®¹*m$-®<m)øPO
```

Inputs in the order \$k,n,p\$.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8HafQ@uKD620yz206dC6Qzu1dF3sDq3TV9HV8tQuPrTOJtkTLJqrogvk5Goe3hHg//@/GZehgQGXgZ4ZAA)

**General explanation of the larger original program:**

Even though the challenge description was just a single sentence, it lead me on a chase down the rabbit hole. After quite a long search, I came across this MathExchange answer: [Probability for the length of the longest run in *n* Bernoulli trials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59738/probability-for-the-length-of-the-longest-run-in-n-bernoulli-trials), for which [the accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/59749/368863) contains the generalized formula for this challenge, originally solved by *de Moivre* in 1738:

$$\mathbb{P}(\ell_n \geq k)=\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor n/k\rfloor} (-1)^{j+1}\left(p+\left({n-jk+1\over j}\right)(1-p)\right){n-jk\choose j-1}p^{jk}(1-p)^{j-1}$$

Where \$\mathbb{P}(\ell_n \geq k)\$ is the probability that a consecutive run of the same unfair coin result with a length \$\ell_n\$ is at least \$k\$ flips. \$p\$, \$k\$, and \$n\$ are as given by the challenge description, with \$p\$ being a decimal probability (e.g. 0.70 for 70%), and \$k\$ and \$n\$ being integers.

**Code explanation:**

```python
0L              # Push pair [1,0]
  α             # Get the absolute difference with the first (implicit) input p:
                #  [1-p,p]
   1Ý           # Push pair [0,1]
     ²ã         # Get the second input n'th cartesian product
                # (creating all n-sized lists with 0s/1s)
       ʒ        # Filter this list by:
        γ       #  Group the 0s/1s into consecutive adjacent items
         O      #  Sum each group
          à     #  Pop and push the maximum
           ³@   #  Check if this largest group of 1s is >= the third input k
       }è       # After the filter: (0-based) index each 0/1 into pair [1-p,p]
         P      # Take the product of each inner list
          O     # Take the sum of all values
                # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

```python
÷               # Integer divide the first two (implicit) inputs: n//k
 L              # Pop and push a list in the range [1,n//k] (its values are j)
  ®             # Push -1
   s            # Swap so the list is at the top
    ©           # Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
     >          # Increase each j in the list by 1
      m         # Pop both, and calculate -1**(j+1) for each
  ®             # Push the list `®` containing j again
   ¹*           # Multiply each j by the first input k
 ²   -          # Subtract each from the second input n
      D         # Duplicate this n-jk list, since we need it again later
       >        # Increase each by 1
        ®/      # Divide each by j
          $     # Push 1 and the third input p
           -    # Subtract: 1-p
            *   # Multiply this to each (n-jk+1)/j
             I+ # And add the third input p to each
 s              # Swap so the n-jk list is at the top again
  ®             # Push list `®` containing j again
   <            # Decrease each j by 1
    c           # Calculate the binomial coefficients of n-jk and j-1
 I              # Push the third input p again
  ®             # Push list `®` containing j again
   ¹*           # Multiply each j by the first input k again
     m          # Pop both, and calculate p**(jk)
 $              # Push 1 and the third input p again
  -             # Subtract again: 1-p
   ®            # Push list `®` containing j again
    <           # Decrease each j by 1 again
     m          # Calculate (1-p)**(j-1)
 )              # Wrap these five lists on the stack into a list of lists
  ø             # Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
   P            # Get the product of each inner list
O               # And finally sum everything together
                # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: Did not know about this formula, was using the markov method and was looking for a trick related to decomposition, this formula is cleaner

Comment: It's funny how golf-languages seem to often prefer to port an approach from other golf-languages...  the 'add the probabilities of all possible outcomes' approach (with explanation) was posted in my R answer substantially before the Jelly implementation of the same approach...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen To me personally, Jelly with Jonathan's explanation is easy to read, and therefore to port to 05AB1E's builtins. I personally have never programmed in R, and although I can read some of it, I can't intuitively understand most of it. Also, reading your explanation, your approach is slightly different because R couldn't hold big enough matrices? The Jelly and this 05AB1E answer generate all possible outcomes once, whereas your R answer seems to loop `1e19` times, and check if at least \$k\$ unfair coin heads are present in a random result. Both are brute-force, but different.

Comment: Yes - of course I get it that Jelly (& the explanation) is likely to be easier to port to O5AB1E's builtins!  Still, the approach is identical to the 116-byte 'sum the probabilities of every possible outcome of n coin flips' R version, although the more-detailed explanation for that is only in the code comments.  Possibly I should get better at explaining...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Ah wait, I was looking at your 92 bytes function instead of 116 bytes.. I will edit my answer to also credit you.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>19</s>  15 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ø.ṗṣ1ZṫɗƇ_⁵AP€S
```

A full program accepting `n`, `k`, and `p` that prints the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f9qZWxsef//w5gu4bmX4bmjMVrhuavJl8aHX@KBtUFQ4oKsU////zEw/zP/MC42)** (`n=100` is too big for such an inefficient program.)

#### How?

Creates all \$2^{n}\$ possible outcomes, filters them to those containing a run of at least \$k\$ heads and then sums the probability of each occurrence.

The probability of a given occurrence is the product of `p`'s and `(1-p)`s identified by heads and tails respectively. For example the chance of `[tails, tails, heads, heads, heads]` is the product of `[(1-p), (1-p), p, p, p]` i.e.  \$p^3(1-p)^{2}\$.

```
Ø.ṗṣ1ZṫɗƇ_⁵AP€S - Main Link: integer n, integer k (p is accessed later)
Ø.              - [0,1]
  ṗ             - ([0,1]) Cartesian power (n)
                  -> all length-n tosses with 0 as heads and 1 as tails
        Ƈ       - filter keep those for which:
       ɗ        -   last three links as a dyad - f(Outcome, k):
   ṣ1           -     split at 1s -> runs of heads
     Z          -     transpose
      ṫ         -     tail from index k -> empty (falsey) if longest run < k
          ⁵     - third program argument, p
         _      - subtract -> valid outcomes with heads: -p; tails: 1-p
           A    - absolute values -> valid outcomes with heads: p; tails 1-p
            P€  - product of each -> valid outcome probabilities
              S - sum -> total probability of any valid outcome
```

---

If we could take the probability of tails (\$1-p\$) instead of heads (\$p\$) 14 byes taking `1-p`, `n`, `k`:

```
C©Ƭṗṣ®ZṫɗƇ⁵P€S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f9qZWxsef//Q8KpxqzhuZfhuaPCrlrhuavJl8aH4oG1UOKCrFP///8uNP8xMP8z)

Answer (score 7):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 66 bytes (-1 @xnor)

```
f=lambda n,k,p:n>=k and(1-p*(n>k))*(1-f(n+~k,k,p))*p**k+f(n-1,k,p)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY9BDoIwEEX3nKJh1ZZiQCNRElh4AC9giEGggRSmTS0LY_AibtjonbyNFWH35mcy78_zrW6mljCOr95wf_c58KTNu0uZI2CCqRjSRKAcShz6imJIBSHUMsfgPcRvw86KUuHZxA-nYL40cC07xHsojJTtFTWdktqgVvfnIi_qyrGmhfFRQkUwJw6X-m9GDaBTGLANC1bbjFkMWGQ5mnlveZ3FDlK6AYO5e7cNJn8cDe5cYnnrCw)

Adapted from my [answer to a similar challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248518/107561). Note that I add memoization in the footer. This in theory doesn't change the result but it greatly accelerates the recursion.

#### How?

Uses the recurrence

\$f(n,k,p)=f(n-1,k,p)+p^k(1-p)(1-f(n-k-1,k,p))\$

(valid for *n*>*k*) which is obtained by accounting for words that have k consecutive heads somewhere in the first n-1 tosses, words that end in a tail followed by k heads and the overlap of these two groups.

Comment: It looks like you can save the space after `and` by rearranging terms

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>129</s> <s>122</s> 116 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes thanks to pajonk (which led to -4 more...)*

```r
function(n,k,p)sum(apply(which(array(T,rep(2,n)),T)-1,1,function(v,r=rle(v))prod(p*v+(1-p)*!v)*(max(r$l[!r$v])>=k)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY9NboMwEIX3nGKiZjEDThQQpt3QU2RXtcgiIFsQ2xoSKKenQKWqaumimyfN3/ve8NQUulKXrjC2UAW7IZ/quy1vxlm0ohGeuvsVlfftiIM2pUbFrEY8C648JsISiTMdYhGLr7tecM5thT2RZ3dBH/YRxgdP4a6nEK/qHXnfvux437/Sc94Q0fQApVa2rMDVkMAaCYwFBXMkGMxNg7PtOI/q1vhu2VJQK8NQunkth9MxkcHPX@Z8iThKCoLv9nLTPvvbWb7JaNFsrU5p9vS4wcqE/M1K/89Ko0/iImsrTjZp6UKbPgA)

Exact solution: calculates the probability of every possible outcome of `n` coin flips, and sums those that contain at least `k` heads-in-a-row.

**How?**

```r
function(n,k,p){
    a=expand.grid(rep(list(1:0),n)) # a is a matrix of all possible outcomes of n flips
                                    # with heads represented as 0, tails as 1
    pvals=apply(a,1,function(v)prod(p*v+(1-p)*!v))
                                    # pvals are the probabilities of each outcome 
                                    # by multiplying the probability of each single flip
    itsarun=apply(a,1,function(v)max(rle(v)$l[!rle(v)$v])>=k)
                                    # itsarun is TRUE if the longest run of 0s in each row is >=k
                                    # (rle(v)$l = length of each run, rle(v)$v = value of each run)
    return(sum(pvals*itsarun))      # return the sum of all the pvals for successful outcomes
}
```

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 98 bytes

```r
function(n,k,p){while((T=T+1)<1e19)F=F+(max((r=rle(sample(1:0,n,T,c(1-p,p))))$l[!r$v])>=k);F/1e19}
```

[Try it online with a low-accuracy version](https://tio.run/##dY5BDoIwEEX3nGKMLtpQEYhFo9YlJ2BnlDQVQgO0pKhojGfHwsoYncVMJvP/f2P6Mi0yfm5TqVKeGt2xPr8qcZFaIUVK0uBnV8gqQyhhiRvgXZBRHLPYRTW/I2SYsbeW140dwcYniiREoGDeWKetWXWYmNntiPesxNt4Yd2vfgqi4EpkoHMIYcSDVMDB4qGTlwK0qh72lFeyaQcVh5xLA0JbGQPfC6nz/TcKSUg8ih3nM57@jI/@J9MTdYcejZu/jNarH6yI0IHVvwE)

Brute-force approach: performs `1e19` series of `n` flips, and counts the number of times we get `k` heads-in-a-row.  With this number of repetitions, the answer has a very high chance of being accurate to 8 decimal places, but there is a low-but-finite chance that this won't be the case...

We need to do them one-after-the-other in a `while` loop (rather than the more idiomatic vectorized [R](https://www.r-project.org/) approach of building a matrix and checking the rows) since the number of iterations needed to obtain 8 decimal places of accuracy is too big to be contained in an [R](https://www.r-project.org/) matrix.
The test link substitutes `1e5` in place of `1e19`, for a lower-accuracy output without timing-out.  Feel free to run the high-accuracy version on your own computer if you have the time to wait.

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 83 bytes

```r
function(n,k,p,m=cbind(rbind(1-p,diag(k)*p),!k:0))Reduce(`%*%`,rep(list(m),n))[k+1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lc7BToQwEAbgO08xZrNJu4wbaChuTHgJr0bZWoo0ZadNYbPx6RHwYhQPXv6k08n/TZxc3RnVDLWlWtXR36qpvZIerSdG6DDgpdJvlhoW18zvAzZWvTPHD4HjnXvMOH8yzVUbdt4f9meMJrDeDiO7cCTOn12av0w70J0ibcC3IGAVwRIomEW42bEDT/3H/NX2NgzLloJW2Qjaz2sVZEchk5@nMoECj5Inyfd6uVlf/t0sX2W6ZLm@sqI8PWxYJcrfVvF/q0i/xCXWUS42tWLRpk8)

Port of [dancxviii's Markov method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249365/95126) - upvote that one - but sadly still longer than [pajonk's R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249376/95126)...

Comment: I'm not sure an answer like this can be valid. It's only going to produce a valid answer most of the time, not all.

Comment: @pxeger - I've added an exact solution, too.

Comment: [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##rY9NboMwEIX3nGKiZjEDThQQJt3QU2RXtWhEQLYgtmUSKKenQKWqquiumyfN3/ve@KkpVMXXrtCm4MLbIZ/qhynv2ho0ohFOcD4oXSpk73nEi/CVw0QYInGhQ0zd44bsXDsii1h83/bC576tsCdy3l7RhX2E8cFRuOspxBt/oN@3rzu/79/oJW@IaHqCUrEpK7A1JLDGAm2AYY4Fg74rsKYd51HdatctWww1aw@lnddyOB0TGfz@Z86aiKOkIPhpLzfts7@d5buMFs3W6pRmz@cNVibkv7DS6Iu4yNqKk01autCmTw)

Comment: @pajonk - Thanks!  The ```which(array(),T)``` trick instead of ```expand.grid``` is really nice!

Comment: Port of [loopy walt's python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249360/55372) is just [70 bytes](https://tio.run/##lY/BisIwEIbvfYqBvSTtVNqSRA/WFxFtQ9fQEJmEqohPX5suC6Ldw16G@ecf/m9mGF3Tn/T3pbHU6Gbw93ps921tbtRdrSfmkDDw1pqW0dZhgazMQ8po5zhPp97tKXd5ieHA03B0WdSzGr@g6zV1J/AGKpghYAk0TBC422sPns6PyTJnGy5xS4PRdoDOT2s1FKtKJu/XsQorXEmeJK/xcjFe/Z0sjzKLVc2qEGqzXmBJVJ8s8X@WyH6Iscyjcukz8Uv7cBSK6IxP).

Comment: @pajonk - go ahead and post it!  At least the 'enumerate all the outcomes & add the probabilities' method seems to still be shortest in Husk (& Jelly) so far...

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES7), 106 bytes

Quickly computes the probability, using the formula [found by Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249334/58563).

```javascript
(n,k,p,q=1-p)=>(g=s=>(x=n-(y=j*k))<0?0:s*(p-~x/j*q)*(h=k=>--k?h(k)*(x-k+1)/k:p**y*q**~-j++)(j)+g(-s))(j=1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcnLDoIwEIXhvU/BcmbagVYjicTBZzFe0JZAscbAxlevdWni5uQ/@dzxdYynxz08eRjPl3SVBIP2OuhJLAeUFjqJeWcZGBZx5BH35mCaSBD4PVeOJiS4iZeW2R9u4POd2SuLlW8C0UIT0ZudUggOVQccMZdYTKdxiGN/KfuxgysU1uhiowtTbhFXv2ZNtvpr9X/bfW2NmD4)

---

## JavaScript (ES12), 58 bytes

Using [loopy walt's recursive formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249360/58563) is much shorter and much slower. This version uses a cache to speed it up (-7 bytes without the cache).

Expects `(k)(p)(n)`.

```javascript
k=>p=>g=n=>g[n]||=n>=k&&p**k*(1-p*(n>k))*(1-g(--n-k))+g(n)
//         \_____/
//          cache
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLz8ldcGiNNulpSVpuhY3rbJt7Qps7dJt84BEdF5sTY1tnp1ttppagZZWtpaGoW6BlkaeXbamJoidrqGrm6cL5Gina-RpQk0ISs7PK87PSdXLyU_XSNMw1tQw0DPV1DA00NTkQpUyA0mZgaQw5SxBckZQOYjJCxZAaAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `ḋ`, 23 bytes

```
2$ÞẊ'2€vLG›¹>;⁰⌐⁰"$İvΠ∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuIsiLCIiLCIyJMOe4bqKJzLigqx2TEfigLrCuT474oGw4oyQ4oGwXCIkxLB2zqDiiJEiLCIiLCIxMFxuM1xuMC42Il0=)

Port of Jelly. Really slow.

Previous answer (much faster):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `ḋ`, 41 bytes

```
ḭɾ:£›u$e¹¥□h*-:›¥/⁰⌐*⁰+$¥‹ƈ?¥?*e⁰⌐¥‹eWƒ*∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuIsiLCIiLCLhuK3JvjrCo+KAunUkZcK5wqXilqFoKi064oC6wqUv4oGw4oyQKuKBsCskwqXigLnGiD/CpT8qZeKBsOKMkMKl4oC5ZVfGkiriiJEiLCIiLCI2XG4xMDBcbjAuNiJd)

Port of 05AB1E.

Answer (score 4):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 53 bytes

```
k->p->g(n)=if(n>=k,p^k*(1-p*(n>k))*(1-g(n---k))+g(n))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWN02zde0KdO3SNfI0bTPTNPLsbLN1CuKytTQMdQu0gNxsTU0QGyivq6sL5GiDVGpCNG8pKMrMK9FI0zDW1DDQM9XUMDSASS1YAKEB)

A port of [loopy walt's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249360/9288). Takes input in the the form `(k)(p)(n)`

---

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 56 bytes

```
f(n,k,p)=Pol((1-y=p*x)/(t=1-x)/(t/y^k+x-y)+O(x^n*x))\x^n
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWNy3SNPJ0snUKNG0D8nM0NAx1K20LtCo09TVKbA11wbR-ZVy2doVupaa2v0ZFXB5QUjMGSEP1hyQWFORUaiQq6NopFBRl5pUAmUogjpJCcmJOjkaajkKipqaOQnS0oYGOgrGOgoGeaSyQa2gA5JqBuGZwriWIaxQbqwkxG-ZGAA)

The generation function of the sequence (for given \$p, k\$) is \$\frac{p^k\ x^k\ (1-p\ x)}{(1-x)(1-x+(1-p)\ p^k\ x^{k+1})}\$.

---

This generation function can be derived from loopy walt's recurrence formula:

\$f(n,k,p)=f(n-1,k,p)+p^k(1-p)(1-f(n-k-1,k,p))\$.

This recurrence formula is valid when \$n>k\$. In addition,
when \$n=k\$, we have \$f(n,k,p)=p^k\$ when \$n=k\$, and \$f(n,k,p)=0\$ when \$n<k\$.

Let \$F(k,p)\$ be the generation function (for given \$p, k\$), we have

\$\begin{align}
F(k,p) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f(n,k,p)\ x^n \\
  &= p^k\ x^k+\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}f(n,k,p)\ x^n \\
  &= p^k\ x^k+\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}(f(n-1,k,p)+p^k(1-p)(1-f(n-k-1,k,p)))\ x^n \\
  &= p^k\ x^k+\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}f(n-1,k,p)\ x^n+p^k(1-p)\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}(x^n-f(n-k-1,k,p)x^n) \\
  &= p^k\ x^k+x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f(n,k,p)\ x^n+p^k(1-p)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(x^{n+k+1}-f(n,k,p)x^{n+k+1}) \\
  &= p^k\ x^k+x\ F(k,p)+p^k(1-p)(\frac{x^{k+1}}{1-x}-x^{k+1}F(k,p))
\end{align}\$.

Solving this equation, we have \$F(k,p)=\frac{p^k\ x^k(1-p\ x)}{(1-x)(1-x+(1-p)\ p^k\ x^{k+1})}\$.

Answer (score 3):

## PARI-GP, 75 bytes

[Port of below solution](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWN73TNPJ0snUKNG01chNLijIrNLK1tYECiTpJOhqJuoa2tkmaWgXaGok2RppaGkk22UDSULdAEyiinWRrm62drakZl6cZna1jGAsxcl9BUWZeiUaahqEBDOgYmhroGOhZmJtqakIUwewHAA) (can run n ~ 1000000000, k ~ 150)

```
f(n,k,p)=(matrix(k++,k,a,b,(a-1==b)*p+(a<2)*(b<k)*(1-p)+(a+b==k+k))^n)[k,1]
```

## Python (Numpy), 104 bytes

Noone has the markov method yet:

The states are the number of consecutive heads starting at state 0, with the final state as state k. State i (i < k) goes to state i+1 with probability p and state 0 with probability 1-p. State k always goes to state k. The matrix is:

\$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 - p & 1 - p & 1 - p & \dots & 1 - p & 0 \\
p & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & p & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & p & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\$

Taking this matrix to the nth power and multiplying it by the vector \$\left[1, 0, 0, \dots, 0 \right]^T \$ gives the answer.

This [solution](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY1NCsIwEIXX5hRZJvaHBARFyN47lCBd9Ce0kwwxRetV3HSjd-ptTLXQ4Q3fvPcW8_rgGFpnp_lSewfUDoAjNYDOB7onW5b3xpZ9s1XEUkWliEO6eB0EwQiRH99DqLPT3IJ6Vt7dGOsSmcblnNTOU0ONpb60TcU6fiY7KIQujFYyw8WYRP4sEig6HaUkQW9sYFAGbx5XdPfKM0gtX3qh-f_ftGLlFw) is not an clean mathematical sum but it is much more computationally efficient then the sum.

```
m=zeros((k+1,k+1))
for i in range(k):
    m[0][i]=1-p
    m[i+1][i]=p
m[k][k]=1
print(matrix_power(m,n)[k][0])
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: Nice answer. But according to [tag:code-golf]'s rule, you need to write either a function or a full program that takes `n,p,k` as input. A snippet that assume `n,p,k` are predefined is not allowed. You also need to include `from numpy import*`.

Answer (score 2):

## Desmos, 80 bytes

```
P(p,k,n)=∑_{j=1}^{n/k}-(-1)^j(p+(n-jk+1)(1-p)/j)nCr(n-jk,j-1)p^{jk}(1-p)^{j-1}
```

[Try it on Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/on5h94g72s) or [prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pgfnarlcg3).

Thanks to Kevin Cruijssen for finding this formula.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.combinatorics math.unicode`, 133 bytes

```
[| n k p | n k /i [1,b] [| j | -1 j 1 + ^ n j k * - :> z z 1 + j
/ 1 p - * p + z j 1 - nCk p j k * ^ * 1 p - j 1 - ^ * * * ] map Σ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY/BTsMwDIbvfYr/vNGuZWISQ@LCAXHhgjhVnZSFdKTtnJCkBxh7Gt6HVypOMyErdv7vty25FTIYN72@PD0/btErR2rAYKQYPI4ivM@paEeSQRtKrJDmuNckeFDLC3KCDuryH0lL86bg1ceoSDK2ToXwaZ2mgLssO@GEqsQaZXGD8yxKbFht/tUtq2tW56n@BqGHRaorjbq62jdg3jHLKy4Vltix3XHDAjm29/jiiLjLVlwtwwXnJdPYnoMe4s40sOOXepIXdYyG77H4/UEz1Wi182HNjI@xxqvZ80HIvpj@AA)

Translation of the formula given in Kevin Cruijssen's [05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249334/97916).

Comment: How many bytes is it without the whitespace? :P

Comment: @thejonymyster 72 bytes. I prefer programs that compile, though.

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>30</s> <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```
ṁoΠm≠²fö≥⁰▲mΣgπḋ2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATIAzf9odXNr///huYFvzqBt4omgwrJmw7biiaXigbDilrJtzqNnz4DhuIsy////MS8y/zX/Ng)

Port of [my R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249333/95126).
Input is arg1=p, arg2=k, arg3=n.

```
                πḋ2     # cartesian arg-3-th power of binary digits of 2
                        # so: all possible combinations of n heads/tails;
        fö              # now consider only those with runs: filter by
            ▲           # the maximum of
             mΣg        # the sums of each group of identical elements
          ≥⁰            # is greater than or equal to arg-2;
                        # now convert the 1s & 0s to probabilities:
   mo -²                # subtract the probability of heads from each 
     a                  # and get the absolute values
                        # so 1s become (1-p) and 0s become p;
ṁo                      # finally map across each group & sum the result
  Π                     # product of the probabilities
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 35 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＮζＩΣＥΦＥＸ²θ⍘ι²№ι×1η×ＸζΣιＸ⁻¹ζ⁻θΣι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYzLCsIwEEX3@YrQ1QRGaSuuurNQcFEp1B@IpdhA01cShf58nBAQcVZzztw73SC3bpaj99dpcfbm9KPfYBUF@@Xhj3fiZlOThVIaC63TUMsFKjVauoa1md@05chXgfwiTd9ayj9BIc8FqXJ21Ca6K90bSLIE@SDCJYrY35GH3yr4aGo1OQMZ8p1UhPUbilN4n6XsxNLj2R9e4wc) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Brute force approach.

```
ＮθＮηＮζ
```

Input `n`, `k` and `p`.

```
ＥＸ²θ⍘ι²
```

Get all of the binary numbers up to `2ⁿ`.

```
Φ...№ι×1η
```

Keep only those with `k` consecutive heads, I mean `1`s.

```
Ｅ...×ＸζΣιＸ⁻¹ζ⁻θΣι
```

Compute their probabilities, which is `pⁱ(1-p)ⁿ⁻ⁱ`, where `i` is the number of `1`s in each relevant row.

```
ＩΣ...
```

Output the grand total.

A 40-byte port of @dancxviii's approach is much more efficient:

```
Ｎθ≔Ｅ⊕Ｎ¬ιηＦＮ«≔⊟ηζ≔⁺⟦×Ση⁻¹θ⟧×ηθη⊞η⁺ζ⊟η»Ｉ⊟η
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY09D4IwEIZn@is6XhM0sLA4GScGCIluxqFitU1ogX44YPzttRRDjNPdPe/HtZzqtqed96UanK2dvDINI9mhvTHioaCiA5Sq1UwyZdkNfm2EpLjuLYh54SFz7zX@c@AXSr5VTT8AD84pOFfWOQPnk5DMwNHJqFdCBZineCTkkuJF5PFc3iSNM3wmMT2FGZtJkN6o0UJZOFBjYcXeZ9sCFSjPMr95dh8) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes inputs in the order `p`, `k`, `n`. Expects `k>1` (+1 byte to support `k=1`). Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `p`.

```
≔Ｅ⊕Ｎ¬ιη
```

Create an array of `1` `1` and `k` `0`s.

```
ＦＮ«
```

Repeat `n` times.

```
≔⊟ηζ
```

Remove the last entry of the array.

```
≔⁺⟦×Ση⁻¹θ⟧×ηθη
```

Multiply the array by `p`, then prefix the sum of the array multiplied by `1-p`.

```
⊞η⁺ζ⊟η
```

Add the previous last entry to the current last entry.

```
»Ｉ⊟η
```

Output the last entry in the array.

I had been planning on working out how to solve the problem using dynamic programming but I'm pretty sure it would have resulted in the same algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 70 bytes

```r
`[`=function(k,n,p)`if`(n<k,0,(1-p*(n>k))*(1-k[n-k-1,p])*p^k+k[n-1,p])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY/BisIwEIbvfYqBvSTtVNqSRA/WFxFtQ9fQEJmEqohPX5suC6Ldw16G@ecf/m9mGF3Tn/T3pbHU6Gbw93ps921tbtRdrSfmkDDw1pqW0dZhgazMQ8po5zhPp97tKXd5ieHA03B0WdSzGr@g6zV1J/AGKpghYAk0TBC422sPns6PyTJnGy5xS4PRdoDOT2s1FKtKJu/XsQorXEmeJK/xcjFe/Z0sjzKLVc2qEGqzXmBJVJ8s8X@WyH6Iscyjcukz8Uv7cBSK6IxP)

Port of [@loopy walt's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249360/55372).

For different approaches in [R](https://www.r-project.org/) see [@Dominic van Essen's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249333/55372).

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 59 bytes

```
kpIf[#>=k,(1-Boole[#>k]p)(1-#0[#-k-1])p^k+#0[#-1],0]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P/v9pIUFQOyZFq1sZ5uto2Go65Sfn5MK5GXHFmgCucoG0cq62bqGsZoFcdnaYJ5hrI5BrNr/gKLMvBIFB4W0aOPYaAM909hoQ4PY/wA)

Port of Python. Takes `f(k)(p)(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 49 bytes

```
1 :'0{_1{[:+/ .*^:(u-1)~(1,~]#0:),.~(*=@i.),~1-['
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DRWs1A2q4w2ro6209RX0tOKsNEp1DTXrNAx16mKVDaw0dfTqNLRsHTL1NHXqDHWj1f9rcqUmZ@QrGOiZKmgYGiikaSoYw0TMQCJgITOYkBFcyPI/AA)

Almost identical to dancxviii's Markov chain approach.