# It's Just Rocket Science, Part 2 - Centrifuge

Tags: code-golf, math

You've [gotten out of Earth's gravity well](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/252264/114332) - good for you! However, you're feeling a bit uncomfortable in zero-gravity, and you want to replicate 1 \$g\$ of force in a centrifuge. Use the [equation for force in a centrifuge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifuge#Mathematical_description):
$$\text{RCF} = \frac{r_\text{m} \, \left(\frac{2 \pi N_\text{RPM}}{60}\right)^2}{g}$$
Where

- \$\text{RCF}\$ is "relative centrifugal force", or the force relative to 1 \$g\$; in this case we want this to be \$1\$.
- \$r_\text{m}\$ is the radius of the centrifuge in meters. You can take this, or a similar quantity - for example, taking it in millimeters.
- \$N_\text{RPM}\$ is the rotational speed in revolutions per minute. You're going to output this.
- \$g\$ is the [local gravitational field of Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Earth) - for this challenge, use the standard value of \$9.80665\;\text{m}/\text{s}^2\$.

In alternate form, when \$\text{RCF} = 1\$:
$$N_\text{RPM} = \dfrac{60\sqrt{\dfrac{g}{r_\text{m}}}}{2\pi}.$$

To clarify: take the radius of the centrifuge, output rotational speed in RPMs, with precision to 6 significant digits. Scoring is standard for [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Test cases (calculated using [SpinCalc](https://www.artificial-gravity.com/sw/SpinCalc/)):

```
1 -> 29.904167719726267
10 -> 9.456528152601877
50 -> 4.229087956071661
87 -> 3.206063305621029
100 -> 2.9904167719726273
103 -> 2.946545199338184
167 -> 2.314053973112157
200 -> 2.1145439780358304
224 -> 1.9980562507828685
250 -> 1.8913056305203755
264 -> 1.8404742955585696
300 -> 1.726517928287568
328 -> 1.651181438643768
400 -> 1.4952083859863137
409 -> 1.4786659280153986
1000 -> 0.9456528152601877
2000 -> 0.6686775183186282
10000 -> 0.2990416771972627
```

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25179/114332) (deleted)

Comment: How accurate is  Pi?

Comment: @MehanAlavi doesn't matter, as long as your final answer is accurate to 6 sigfigs

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 24 bytes

```python
lambda r:29.904167/r**.5
```

### [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZJNbtswEIWBLnkKQSspsFXODOeHAdxVb9F04aARKkCxDFtd5CzZGCjaM_QsPU2HlhygWQgU5uN7M3zk6-_jy_x9Olx-9ruHXz_mfmt_xv3z47d9dbrH3OWYQPTj6e6u4wX__fB5fjrPu7quodp-qt42KWRFQdEAsYDcJRZGA0aJYKqBr_XUIeZomlmigggE01KnDqNEIYosCBGz-1wF2OX_Oig5oZUk4cSQM5GBpeC7FkCQIlNWAkBgDXjzAkicHFgkNoopIKZCwLtYac1RDU2MAy4DQ2cZylT-YSRlJ7JqLMWkCTMzG0uWQHHV-KQMmtG9lMUCoS3Ay2CQyCSROkg3Rcpub2ScTQhIneSVqImwe0XwM5mUZK6i6AG8CxnfkIh5ZgxGYOJzXFUrw3eR-m2GYap21ZdxOM_N8_7Y9OO0nzdjdz6Ow9zURVe3bdtPp2qshkNVXsENPhzq9msoaNhMBQ7Tfaiq42k4zI2XNn0ztJv947kpP9upbZfHdLks6z8)

### Explanation

The expression we're trying to calculate is

$$N_\text{RPM} = \dfrac{60\sqrt{\dfrac{g}{r_\text{m}}}}{2\pi}.$$

If we rearrange terms, we can turn this into

$$N_\text{RPM} = \dfrac{60\dfrac{\sqrt{g}}{\sqrt{r_\text{m}}}}{2\pi} 
= \dfrac{60\sqrt{g}}{2\pi\sqrt{r_\text{m}}}
= (\dfrac{60\sqrt{g}}{2\pi})\frac{1}{\sqrt{r_\text{m}}}$$

Since we know \$g = 9.80665\$ (it's constant), we can calculate the value of the \$(\dfrac{60\sqrt{g}}{2\pi})\$ term, getting approximately \$29.904167\$. In other words,

$$N_\text{RPM} \approx 29.904167\frac{1}{\sqrt{r_\text{m}}}$$

Comment: I guess the link is broken.

Comment: @MehanAlavi The link works for me?

Comment: Yeah it is fixed now. I dont know why it wasn't working. BTW, I dont really understand your awnser, Can you please explain it? Thanks :)

Comment: @MehanAlavi Is this explanation good?

Comment: Yeah thank you. What a creative mind you have got :)

Answer (score 3):

### [Python](https://python.org), <s>53</s> <s>52</s> <s>41</s> 39 bytes

```
lambda a:30*(9.80665/a)**0.5/3.14519265
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/5fYRvzPycxNyklUSHRythAS8NSz8LAzMxUP1FTS8tAz1TfWM/QxNTQ0sjM9H9BUWZeiUaFhqGmJhecbYDEMQVy/gMA)

- -2 bytes thanks to The Thonnu

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Comment: I think you can remove the `x=` and just put ``x=\`` in the header code, saving you 2 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), <s>16</s> <s>15</s> 13 bytes

```
8825.985÷½÷ØP
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700KzUnp3LBgqWlJWm6FhstLIxM9SwtTA9vP7T38PbDMwKWFCclF0NlYaoA)

This is my first Jelly answer, so it can almost certainly be golfed.

- -1 byte thanks to MehanAlavi

Comment: instead of 1/2*60 Write 30. Saved 3 bytes

Comment: can you explain what `÷ØP` does? Thanks!

Comment: @DialFrost ÷ is division and ØP gets pi (the constant). So ÷ØP means "divide by pi".

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 64 bytes

```go
import."math"
func f(r float64)float64{return 29.904167/Sqrt(r)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ddJNatwwFAdw6HJOYWY1htR933ra9QiFnsCEOB2a8aTGswo5STZDoYfoUdoT9BiVJSejKXRhBOan_3t60sv3--P552N_-7W_v2sO_X7c7A-Px2nutsNh3v44zcN7__Xx9d-hn79sN8NpvG2G3dQMD8d-NmnX9Wm6m0_T2FDsIgha-PD52zTvpva55Px-9ydvXcrs2uZp82naj_PDuMObFIftzWVnwBjIyEJ7QZAVJBY7UVNyVDJAD5XSrHRR0hFF8BDVIKAZXpSHRXlIijsCA2MGNUKgWFdcSy5p1MWr1gLXkAvkAsVUFGNkdnSpnOW6acmOUUA5BkYk1OoQVArTWhhRVJJzYHWGKpBIMiRJEFOHvpxCITi5uVawzIXyYLDziMt500fAQWtoJdFKogtIEIqq6mrRLpBLjwwlMY1EMURKhYOaV448O_LskkJHYTfhUDspebLmSUytObtGN0YONYwFxgKDm2kqDJhm6XZ1fa_3t2RCupf_vRqCt4kXaubpphWd0S0d6jr1LbZg-udltJv1wZ_PZf0L)

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 16 bytes

```
29.904167/*.sqrt
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYu9DoMwEINfxUKIoQNcLtdAxM@roA5kompJWBDqs4ejg@XPsv1d4ury@0AVMGb2tScxrm0eddrinnuk14GinDFOOAPK@VcgfCIGA0N4ErpWgVQW@gMrMwtYK3YCq9lyB1EX8veW7hH9iaZ8AQ)

I searched in vain for some short combination of Unicode characters whose numerical values could be combined in some way to get a number very close to the constant factor here.  Oh well!

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 21 bytes

```factor
[ -.5 ^ 29.904167 * ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdLLSsNQEAbgfZ/iuBUa5n5RcCtu3IgrUSilRRfW2saFiM9eT5u0iWIggZCPmf/MZDmbt2@b3f3dze31RXmdtc/N8mM1b1/eVtvDa1lvFm37ud68rNqyXbx/LFbzxbZcTiZfk1Iv3D/KWZleFcomQdDcMZ2MzDsBJ5GNqCkFKhlgeAd0ANIQJYSnGjia4QGEnwA3BAbGDGqEQNm3gFOIJn@FcO4Fj4SYimImc2BIB8wHwCignM6IhNqlpHEPRFGpIIA1GLoSRHIUWFPEPqKCB4WFdkJhEJG4P0W9Cdi1FzaqEQLiQqmqoZZ2EAyjGvWEip5Ue7hadIBiAPUzBgqHCXsPZFxBsrYPDs0wRvZe5Eh4mGntAVhnEnacOPQC6jz/2SqNhVnUjSgGY1hNe6oBR0F/1jb53j2UaaPlafivynl53L3O1qXZ/QA)

Port of 97.100.97.109's [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252634/97916).

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 13 bytes

```
29.9041677?√/
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiMjkuOTA0MTY3Nz/iiJovIiwiIiwiMVxuMTBcbjUwIl0=)

Comment: You might be able to save a few bytes by a) losing precision b) Replacing the constant with (something close to) its reciprocal and swapping it with the sqrt

Answer (score 1):

## x86 32-bit machine code, 16 bytes

```
68 98 90 5F 44 D9 04 24 D8 74 24 08 D9 FA 58 C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVJNj5swED3jXzGlioQDQQ4fWZJsetpjq1bRSq2UzYHYhlgidgokJYry10vHdLdq0wPDmzfPM48xfFJy3vfvlebVSUh4bFqhTLj/QP6hKrW752qlS8uRyugShDntKgmFV1Qmb0HTJZyNEiC18OiS5M0BPFi7HgnLyuzyCgpSLJxwd2klsG6WESdssCG2yOZJGKXzKHlgbJ5OszROiVNUAp6@fl4/wZfnNWxkc9wiKdT5jgUfMltpvtctcY7mCDLviFPLlqCTBaEuoBuidAuHXGnPgrwueQB8n9cwHmNypuRKHG5004Ktt3yzhRVcpwFMWQApPtmDxcyGGMMM08imUZRgsIpohii2XBxlASQWJWw@HGODmv3G7LYkjh3T4YwJzrjgmyH3Y69wG57vd/AI04wSxzniztvCc0epglE4zT4WL9oNrMFuG@DuB0DxA/8oX/SnnO@VlsCNkAvX1rrXAcLA9U0HIxZ9w1aXleeddKNKLcWwkjEt6Kbz/S1d3uDV0n8KtPhuBfc0LvxvK@CNFNj7bujgurNFvJhTra2dG@n7n7yo8rLpJ4c4woA/zQrPyuoX)

Following the `cdecl` calling convention, this takes \$r_{\mathrm{m}}\$ on the stack and returns \$N_{\mathrm{RPM}}\$ on the FPU register stack.

In assembly:

```
f:  .byte 0x68                  # Push a 4-byte value onto the stack:
    .single 894.259247009518535 #  this value, which equals (60/2π)²·g.
    fld DWORD PTR [esp]         # Put that value onto the FPU register stack.
    fdiv DWORD PTR [esp + 8]    # Divide it by the value given.
    fsqrt                       # Take the square root.
    pop eax                     # Pop the value added to the stack.
    ret                         # Return.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 13 bytes

```
29.9041677%%:
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxl0TtWw1AMBNA+q0iTEqPRd5SCjXBos/8loGeSOEDh6nr0e7er9tbiyKrL5Xo63T7xdX4/v32cD0CXpmYtlLv25pGhRGgKWAvjgb6ptrA6UgqZGGTd0TaVlDSTSIVo72UfUd36V9eyne1gz/BAtxlBX5r1VINLWJcBilhD6UtpwMNHKRY0WWFVvzOmM9dMIUVlMhY/d8LGxpp5PhWr2DmPNF28XDsiGNk5bHKkZ5lAtU7piuRS5VPHQLgx3WpXf8l6T0sao5kGq5374GJmTGnB7M78OegjLnOyf0+lr57JuXeABuYMeM8fP+ifN/kGRsh0oA==)

Dead simple. Doesn't display correctly with all numbers correct up to all precision, but that isn't a requirement anyway.

Explanation:

```
29.9041677%%:    Main program. Takes implicit input
            :    Takes input from the right side
           %     Square root
          %      Divide with
29.9041677       Literal number "29.9041677"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 21 bytes

```
Ｉ∕₂∕⁸⁸²⁵·⁹⁸⁵Ｎ≕math.pi
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwyWzLDMlVSO4sDSxKDUoPx8uYmFhZKpnaWGqo@CZV1Ba4leam5RapKGpqamj4J5aEpZYlJmYlJOqoZSbWJKhV5CpBJTRtP7/39DA4L9uWQ4A) Link is to verbose version of code.  Calculates the answer as accurately as possible. Explanation: The constant `8825.985` arises from the following calculation:

$$ \frac{60\sqrt{\frac{g}{r_\text{m}}}}{2\pi}=\frac{30\sqrt{\frac{g}{r_\text{m}}}}\pi=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{900g}{r_\text{m}}}}\pi $$

```
    ⁸⁸²⁵·⁹⁸⁵            Literal number `8825.985`
   ∕                    Divided by
            Ｎ           Input number
  ₂                     Take the square root
 ∕                      Divided by
             ≕math.pi   Python variable `math.pi`
Ｉ                       Cast to string
                        Implicitly print
```

13 bytes by porting @adam's approximation:

```
Ｉ∕²⁹·⁹⁰⁴¹⁶⁷₂Ｎ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwyWzLDMlVcPIUs/SwMTQzFxHIbiwNLEoNSg/v0TDM6@gtMSvNDcptUhDEwSs//83NDD4r1uWAwA) Link is to verbose version of code.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
tz•1Íãǝ•*6°/
```

Port of [*@97.100.97.109*'s Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252634/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/pOpRwyLDw72HFx@fC2RpmR3aoP//v6EBEAAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/kqpHDYsMD/ceXnx8LpClZXZog/5/nf/RhjqGBjqmBjoW5kCGARAb6xiamesYAdlGRiY6RkApIzMTHWMg39jIQscESJsYWILUGoAUGYBZBrEA).

A port of [the Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252624/52210) would be 1 [byte](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) longer:

```
•‡»µ•₄/I/tžq/
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOiRw0LD@0@tBXEamrR99QvObqvUP//f0MDIAAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/Rw2LHjUsPLT70FYQq6lFv1K/5Oi@Qv3/Ov@jDXUMDXRMDXQszIEMAyA21jE0M9cxArKNjEx0jIBSRmYmOsZAvrGRhY4JkDYxsASpNQApMgCzDGIB).

**Explanation:**

```python
t              # Take the square root of the (implicit) input
 z             # Calculate 1 divided by this value
  •1Íãǝ•*      # Multiply it by compressed integer 29904167
         6°/   # Divide it by 1000000 (6**10)
               # (after which the result is output implicitly)

•‡»µ•          # Push compressed integer 8825985
     ₄/        # Divide it by 1000: 8825.985
       I/      # Divide it by the input
         t     # Take the square root of that
          žq/  # Divide it by PI (3.141592653589793)
               # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E answer of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•1Íãǝ•` is `29904167` and `•‡»µ•` is `8825985`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Port of the [Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252634/58974).

```
29.904#§/U¬
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=MjkuOTA0I6cvVaw&input=MTAwMDA)