# Can you perform swaps?

Tags: code-golf, string, balanced-string

Today's problem is easy. You're given two strings A and B of equal length consisting of only the characters `(` and `)`. Check whether after any number of operations you can make both strings balanced or not. The only operation allowed is swapping A[i] and B[i], where i is an arbitrary index.

Here is the definition of a balanced string.

- An empty string is a balanced string.
- If s is a balanced string, `"(" + s + ")"` is a balanced string.
- If x and y are balanced, `x + y` is balanced.

Tests:

```
( ) -> false
() () -> true
((())) ()()() -> true
()())) ((()() -> true
)))((( ((())) -> false
)))))) )))))) -> false
))))))) ))))))) -> false
()))))) (((((() -> false
```

Shortest code wins.

Comment: Can we use true and false in stead of ( and )?

Comment: Or even better `1` and `-1`

Comment: You can represent the open and close parentheses as anything you want.

Comment: By "a few" do you mean "any number of" or 3 or less?

Comment: How do you define "Balanced" ?

Comment: This ought to provide a balanced-parentheses checker to call.

Answer (score 9):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), <sup><del>204</del> <del>179</del> <del>147</del> <del>132</del> <del>123</del> <del>98</del> <del>90</del></sup> 80 bytes

```rust
|a,b|a.iter().zip(b).fold([0;3],|[c,d,f],(&e,g)|[c+e+g,d^e^g,f.min(c+d)])==[0;3]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVNLboMwEF10VU4xYVHZik0-VaUo3yM0i6obRCoCdmQJTASmitpwkm6yaI_Qw7SnKeQDhISkyMj2zLzHDHrv4zOMI_Vt6pQyVygRSJ2A3m13O7r1Q7kE3xYSYXjXPKaA97lEz8wZit6Y7HdMx_Mg8GD0FStOez_TtU3ma9sQioUIG29iiebY4IHnIrM9uLfI2nSIS7hF0B0jC5xem6y5IO6MzRaEG376PafpYguPRlvAjvf3xh-ApvEgBMUi9eLYEQMhwdQgfdArcxpmxyKQH7jtRQwT7baSo-eSBAosgZoSelKjwrjCsl00f48Aea4WTi_gr8FpCbhfZ9G0ZkB6lK82UJv9F8t1pgs__RJZMWsxYokmk0arBU-pYCATTASPU3A8W_gR2CEDJ4hlKlO2sv2lx6KylM6w1rdUI4Vq0QlzFW2lPst6WIZCKk82kM7RKjVff_gwSUD189NhoCwySVLLcpS7wmgbjhdIhjAprGJ0DsGjaLd8ORQMtERLdq7bbHb7Hw)

- -9 bytes thanks to [SUTerliankov](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/263496/can-you-perform-swaps/263499?noredirect=1#comment576827_263499)
- -2 bytes thanks to [SUTerliankov](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/263496/can-you-perform-swaps/263499?noredirect=1#comment576943_263499)

Radically new algorithm. We know the only possible failure case is if:

- We get 2 simultaneous closing parenthesis when the nesting level is 0
- We get 2 different closing parenthesis when the nesting level is 0

We use `d` to store if there currently is an odd or even number of unequal pairs. If the nesting level `c-d` is negative, we fail. If the nesting level is not 0 or the number of unequal pairs is not even at the end we fail.

`d^((e^!g)+1)/2` should be 1 if e=g and 0 otherwise.

Uses `1` to represent an opening parenthesis and `-1` for closing.

Comment: [123](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVNLbsIwEJW6a04xZFF51HEErBA09BbdIFQZx0aRQhISU6ECJ-mGRXsEDtOepk4CISAotR15fu_NjDz5-MwWudmNXM5VEJowiV0Ct9vudtzxN9cxzEQYM4SVEykDuq9j9qLkU9gb0v5GPpwkSQT-18Jo3vterQVN1sILjcoYeu9hyibo6SQKGGuT3UhrJikgjcQeFE1xvbLcLKU5-kx5M5tvio8BWVEsC1HigKWlfY40L60pki4tEnGDvr9nrkr4udsNwHF0koFRuXmVIlcQxjBy7tmbkq1RZ0xQCryQtIhyhVQ7CXgdcFBMtjgNqQ6vvxNA7bsK53_gb8F5A7g_F9E18VmD_MR_XsBV779YbjNdZrtJduz12GKDZmwHFOwqhnSaGPBBs_rtvbYnoyRWDOk4EF7nYMRBCU2zMDZR3GKukGYhoj6s-s8bUMtUSaOCvVrgocBXuv1ZbLombbepnGYQea4y02oU1gXfLwhswMbZVNO73Vb3Lw)

Comment: Counterexamples: https://gist.github.com/huynhtrankhanh/5fe464ed35088f207d3d8404ad331f8c

Comment: @HuỳnhTrầnKhanh You copied my answer incorrectly, the counterexamples work properly in the version as I posted them here. You write `e_min.min(g)` where it whould be `e_min.min(e_max)`

Comment: @HuỳnhTrầnKhanh https://gist.github.com/mousetail/dd0a3ac3e2dce90b384f5fa9090bb453/revisions

Comment: Cheap -2 [on the surface](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVNNboJAFF50VU7xZGFm4gyCSROjovtu2kXTjdEWYcZMgoOBoTGtnKQbF-0Rehh7mkJQQCq1ZMjM-_m-eS_zvfePMI7U11SnlHlCiUDqBPSe2bP02Z5yCStHSIThTfOZAj7gEj0ydyT6Y3LYMR0vgsAH-zNWnPb3z1uHLLaOIRQLETZexRotsMED30PIJCZRYcww2SKXeIRjgtqMLHFqdlhnSbw5QmzeWuKOhbs9wtttd2x7GNt2ic3v-b66HYKm8SAExSL15DoRAyFhqkH6oRfmtqbWjEBx4I4fpRdr17UYPRckQEvwwcgLr6Tkixb_CaCINcLpH_hLcFoBHtZZdEFca5CexOsFNEb_xXKZ6TzbRbKy17LFCk327t0uPKRqgEwNEdzdg-s7YhWBEzJwg1immmQbZ7X2WVTVyRnW5pIapFBP-sVcR8_SocpqWIdCKl-2kM7RJp20wehmkoAaFKdjQ5lnkqTzyVEhecM0XD-QDGFSzoFhHZ0n3l7VOCYMtURL8pHa7fL9Bw)

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript, <s>109</s> <s>107</s> ... 95 bytes

*Thanks to @Arnauld for saving 2 bytes*

```javascript
b=(x,k=0n)=>k<0?0:x?b(x/4n,k+x%4n-2n):!k
f=(l,r,k=0n,x=k&(r^l))=>b(l^x)&b(r^x)||k<l&&f(l,r,++k)
```

returns `false` (for `false`) or `1` (for `true`).

Encodes expressions as base four numbers with `3` for `(` and `1`  for `)`

Helper functions for converting strings to the corresponding base 4 numbers

```javascript
e=(s)=>s?4n*e(s.slice(1))+(s[0]=='('?3n:1n):0n
h=(x,y)=>f(e(x),e(y))

h(")))(((","((()))") // -> false
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ddFRbsIgGAfw7JVbrIn1_61oUftgGllvsAssc0kdnQZCE5kJJt5kLz5sh9pOM9rqTLYKL8D_9wGB9w9bv6jj8XP3Vo3mX8-lhOdaCkvyXi9EIXJflPBpZrlO_CCzo6ml_FazSsLwbUu5lzrGdmkoFJUwS09xGeaeDge9MHFctTRJNHXHfN88MCXhAndFZu8U3NiZzUphQpTAPYonKYcYFjObT8JxwrJ1c699KKig4Ikr7IkYW9XW1UaNTf2KNSJEPKIoBH_XKQToTQCiLm16b-1Z4IoIcchOglqRpv9Nt8tpcN1cUL_Cr0LbGtU96_kXfwA)

*I was unable to verify the last two Test-cases, as the function exceeded the maximum recursion depth (which as far as I known is allowed for code-golf)*

## Explanation

`b` checks if a the expression encoded by the given number is balanced, by counting the difference of `3` digits minus `1` digits and returning 0 if the intermediate count goes below zero,
or if the final count is not exactly zero.

`f` checks for all binary numbers `k` less than `l` (swapping the outer brackets cannot balance the expression) if swapping the bits of the two inputs at the positions that are one in `k` will result in a pair of balanced strings.
Swapping a bit has no effect if it is the low bit of a base 4 digit where both numbers have a `1` bit, if it is the high bit it will swap the characters that the given positions in the strings.

---

## JavaScript, 108 bytes

```javascript
b=(x,k=0n)=>k<0?0:x?b(x/4n,k+x%4n-2n):!k
f=l=>r=>eval("for(v=0,k=0n;k<l;k++)v|=b(l^k&(r^l))&b(r^k&(r^l));v")
```

uses for-loop to prevent crash due to recursion limit

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dZHfSsMwGMXxtm9hwO18tpuZ9kLafe21zyAO7EydJKTQaOnAN_FmF_pQ-jSm64ogbQL5d34n5yP5-LTVkzocvt5ey8XttykYbaRZWuJMr2UukzYv0F7FNtJhexHbxbWl5FwHJRvOas5U82ggyqpGw_LoTPXapDoMqXnnAmajZ6g3hmhW-HnYpI2gPvPn7C5QDOcDXR7bSwW3dOZlq7AiCuHu5QPzHPP8xiYrny1tsOuK3HtDCYWWyI97oiDYVtZVRi1N9YwdBEQkSHjh_zl5AaMKQNSrXR_1DgQmCC977UTQBNHfcVpMEX_IeCUDg2PrmP5Fh9_8BQ)

Answer (score 6):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 59 bytes

```javascript
a=>b=>(h=u=>u<d|!a[i]?u|d:h(u+=p=a[i]+b[i++],d^=!p))(i=d=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDBboMwDIbvPIV7whY03WWXdga1Um899cqYGiCsTLQgCFOldc/OEkrXdbvMkWL5@@1fid/ku2zTpqj19Fhlqs@5lxwkHOCeOw66p@w8kVERh905m@@x87hmW3tJVHhe7GcvPKmJsOCMH6jfAIN4dLYmTU12tGp1KlvVGrBzEAimAeSybJWDBDiUuulMhUhkiT03SheKd9QgQ2Ac@TakIWBMv/CV3z3gAnCIH8JO6KY4IIm2LguN7vPRJXGQNZ6AAziNeAYYzs0MhTOixe2nIq@atUz3iJH0IfFBxWTnPhyAtDq2GpZmGZEQQsaDa2pVczGDiy6EsIE5bI3ltX819if/7F@bfnXR7b7cq1KVSpTVKxqdYZKj9VzGNORVTD78Qcb0kxb9Fw)

Input arrays of numbers: `0.5` for `(`, `-0.5` for `)`. Output falsy (0) for "can be balanced", truthy (non-zero) for "cannot be balanced".

Construct a string `c` using inputs `a` and `b` by:

- if the i-th characters match, aka. `a[i]==b[i]`, then `c[i]=a[i]`
- Otherwise, they mismatch. For the k-th mismatch (1-indexed), `c[i]=')'` when k is odd, and `c[i]='('` when k is even.

Test if `c` is balanced and there are even number of mismatching.

In above code, `u-d` is how many unclosed "(" in string `c`. `d` is a boolean, truthy when next mismatch should be "(".

I’m *feeling* its correctness. Although I don’t have a mathematical proof to it. However, at least no testcase rejects it currently.

Comment: Half the mismatches must go each way. From any balanced (A,B), we can do two swaps, get closer to (C,...), and stay balanced.

Answer (score 5):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), <del>165</del> 136 bytes

Port of [@mousetail's Rust answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263499/110802) in Scala.

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVTfS8NADH73rwhDJGFnXRUcFFtwPu9p@DREbvWuVGo7e@dYO/q3z7RjbtN1lGGhND@/fClJTCgTuc5m7yq0MJZxCqsLgDel4YMVlHlkPHjMc1lMJzaP0@iFPHhOYws@R3IowEImoD3AifqcjgqrXgT8iAR@AKMsS5RMOWONUszID1BCGc9hRs6NV@chDsSAiFahNApDgaUoiONCRyfSjuV849BiwcYmXvdLsegXJFgqWCqJKh0nVuUY@UHkvLqBP7i6YuGWBarUMjbWbOr4Pq23xK0y9omxDbOrgZuOoGkGXcdmdRfUNIR47dLOomVi@HssXsBh6Cmfzb9aUY5Je9ntyqmarWDnMOyC25mk@38MOxE4XtE9m96JRv8Oi8PDmuA94Z8/0uJpgxi2Qgyp@8gS9PvQjdbvlKNFmhq0uQ86ywG3ewYP17udo@bY1M@cT4tNUjS9y9XWzTtcwb56W4FazvlQqTfvwHFXCYgyWxs17qUL2EumqrehVV3Ub7X@Bg)

Saved 29 bytes thanks to the comment of @corvus_192

```scala
(a,b)=>(a zip b)./:(Seq((0,0))){case(c,(z,y))=>c.flatMap{case(f,v)=>Seq((f+z,v+y),(f+y,v+z))}filter(g=>g._1>=0&&g._2>=0)}exists((0,0)==)
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVRRa9swEH7Pr/goo9wR1cQutBCWwrqnwvpU@lRCUBLJeGh2ZqmjXfBvzyQncZ02DqbswZZO33133x062YU0crMp5j/VwuFeZjnWA2CpNH55g2SZ2jG@laV8fXpwZZanUx7jMc8cJrUn8Eca6DHoQf1@un11airQbBmTG9wWhVEy9wSSAvP6bEsFZPQ3W9GcI12Y5Q@lXR2G7nIn4H88JRqJETNjDVoILyzQd2RgEWkj3b1ceViHuA2CIIJIR7MYQ0/zq4C3kp2VsEAbTQ7QmLmJVEU6M06VlIYEaaDcTDDC@XkwktrYe1eResmsszTDxJc7Eh7aYtWgaZZT1n2XVlnfkSByxw2VUxy5InSOxVb/RcxvJ1oa69dj/r6YA9dTmCufO6Mc27XY3capnJ3BPqOwT9zeIuP/p7CXgOMZ40/LO1Hox8sS7rGhK6YPHelAukJcd4a45v5XljEcop@s95SjSeocvB0zXZSg/Zzh68XbzHHz9Kz8a@ZMTvbsy3oP@@Gu0DaTCupl5d9GtRwfAJeVQFq4cKipRRdokbk6209/@KrBZvMP)

```scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val f: (Seq[Byte], Seq[Byte]) => Boolean = (a, b) => {
      a.zip(b).foldLeft(Seq[(Int, Int)]((0,0))) { (c, de) =>
        c.flatMap { f => 
          Seq((f._1 + de._1, f._2 + de._2), (f._1 + de._2, f._2 + de._1))
        }.filter(g => g._1 >= 0 && g._2 >= 0)
      }.exists(_ == (0, 0))
    }

    val testCases = Seq(
      (Seq(1.toByte), Seq((-1).toByte), false),
      (Seq(1.toByte, (-1).toByte), Seq(1.toByte, (-1).toByte), true),
      (Seq(1.toByte, 1.toByte, 1.toByte, (-1).toByte, (-1).toByte, (-1).toByte), Seq(1.toByte, (-1).toByte, 1.toByte, (-1).toByte, 1.toByte, (-1).toByte), true),
      (Seq(1.toByte, (-1).toByte, 1.toByte, (-1).toByte, (-1).toByte, (-1).toByte), Seq(1.toByte, 1.toByte, 1.toByte, (-1).toByte, 1.toByte, (-1).toByte), true),
      (Seq((-1).toByte, (-1).toByte, (-1).toByte, 1.toByte, 1.toByte, 1.toByte), Seq(1.toByte, 1.toByte, 1.toByte, (-1).toByte, (-1).toByte, (-1).toByte), false),
      (Seq.fill(6)((-1).toByte), Seq.fill(6)((-1).toByte), false),
      (Seq.fill(7)((-1).toByte), Seq.fill(7)((-1).toByte), false),
      (Seq(1.toByte) ++ Seq.fill(6)((-1).toByte), Seq.fill(6)(1.toByte) ++ Seq((-1).toByte), false)
    )

    for (testCase <- testCases) {
      println(s"${testCase._1} ${testCase._2} expected: ${testCase._3}, got: ${f(testCase._1, testCase._2)}")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My rust answer now uses a radically different algorithm, adapting it may save you some bytes :)

Comment: 131 bytes: `b=>_.zip(b)./:(Seq((0,0))){case(c,(z,y))=>c.flatMap{case(f,v)=>Seq((f+z,v+y),(f+y,v+z))}filter(g=>g._1>=0&&g._2>=0)}exists((0,0)==)`

Answer (score 5):

Oops, this doesn't work. Currently being kept as a placeholder.

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>92</s> <s>91</s> 90 bytes

```c
c;i;r;t(a,b,l)int*a,*b;{for(c=i=0,r=!(l&1);i<l;c+=a[i]+b[i++])r&=c>0|a[i]>0&b[i]>0;r&=!c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVPbboIwGL73KX4lI62UDeoxqXC3J5h3jBgosDVhuCBLzBzPzuoJO2RESQl8x5Q/lJtvnFcVZ4LlrEABCUmKRVYMAzIM2S5Z54g7wrFI7vRRqtuYiUXKuOEEnvCN0BOG4eNcd7hr/ewp19LDw4NJss9ZWWki4@lXFMNiU0Ri/fju9rQoTkQWw/L5ZYm2GApUxJtC07aatrIJXAAlsBHf8TpRDRiezqzcKMYMPnP5kqDBQ/SaDQjkmPUkAR@ByABh2PVAXntm32KvbM8HB3Z2yRoCPQpmU6F1hECLSP8XR0ryuMz6vrKqPbW3zTr@s5/u2rFS2906ObeaSt9pXVnprZ81bWvtcNM73LPu7tYEvTMxb8z6hkBzNsqQpPdgPvz58jBdAFXBSAVjFUxUMFXBTAVzCcrqFw)

Returns in boolean r, takes the length and arrays where `(` is 1 and `)` is -1.

Less golfed variation:

```c
int retFlag;
int test (int* a, int* b, int length) {
    int counter = 0;
    retFlag = !(length & 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        retFlag &= counter > 0 || (a[i] > 0 && b[i] > 0);
        counter += a[i] + b[i];
    }
    retFlag &= !counter;
}
```

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>73</s> 71 bytes by @c--

```c
c;r;t(a,b,l)int*a,*b;{for(c=r=l&1;l--;c+=*b+++*a++)r|=c<-*b**a;r=r<!c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZLbToMwGMfveYrPEU1bqIaOHZKCdz6Bu1OzQAElQTAFk0Xk2bE7YWVINlLS/Po/AF8Q9FWIthVc8goFdmhnOM0rEtgk5HVSSCR86Wc3Ds8o5cLySWhZFgksC8tvX3iUhIQEXPrSuxK8ac00F9lnFINXVlFa3L7dG2YUJ2kew@rhcYU2GD6kekCCJtfRcz6xoUJVXFamuTHNtaOwA2ZDmX7FRaIbMNwdT1ULxpgbaof3IM0BYagNUNf2ZJtx1s7TC/hQOw3vCWwv0L7CuogNAyL7X5xqyf2i3X1i1Xs675DV/fM@47WuVjveOju2Uq3vsE6s7NzPmg@1jrjZBe7FePdggl2YWPZmfUagPxttSMq7M@9@ewfzX2A6THVwdZjpMNdhocNSQdP@AA)

=======================

Operating hypothesis (WRONG): The strings can be swapped into both being balanced if and only if their length is even and both `F(A, B)` and `F(B, A)` are balanced, where `F(X, Y) := {X[0], Y[0], X[1], Y[1], X[2], Y[2], ...}`.

Reset edit: Previous program relied on caller manually setting internal variables. 3 bytes saved by @c--

Edit R+1: -1 byte from moving stuff into the conveniently empty for loop declaration.

Edit R+2: -1 byte from moving stuff into the empty for loop body. Thanks @c--

Edit R+3: c-- saved two bytes

Comment: the code should be self-contained, that is, you should reset `c`, `n`, `i` and `r` in the function

Comment: Oh, I misinterpreted "Use global variables to initialize things to zero" on the tips page.

Comment: also, should `t>=0` be `n>=0`?

Comment: Yeah I noticed that after latest revision.

Comment: yeah, that tip is meant for full programs, you can use it in a function, but you can't rely on the caller setting up the environment for you.

Comment: Counterexample: ())()) (()(()

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vSdabtCMrDHPVn70pg4qB0yY-twU4ocmeOhIUV5817Oyh4_FjqDs-r_Z73gSnKSmox3UrH9UsobxUW3/pub

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ZŒpÄṂȯṪƊ€oṚ$Ạ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a pair of lists of \$\{1,-1\}\$ representing `(` and `)` respectively and yields \$0\$ if balancable or \$1\$ if not (i.e. outputs the inverse).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/q6KSCwy0PdzadWP9w56pjXY@a1uQ/3DlL5eGuBf///4@ONtRR0AViKAXBsToK0RAxZNnYWAA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/q6KSCwy0PdzadWP9w56pjXY@a1uQ/3DlL5eGuBf8f7t5yaOvDHZv8dbUeNcxJS8wpTn3UMBfILCkqBbEOt9tbA3kKNroKQJ61ZuT//xoKmlwamgoaQFJDQ1MTxAJBLhAB4mmAeUAmkKUAUQLigeQgFJQH44J0QvgaYAA2SQNkqgYA).

#### How?

```
ZŒpÄṂȯṪƊ€oṚ$Ạ - Link: pair of lists of -1 and 1 := ) and ( respectively
Z             - transpose
 Œp           - Cartesian product
   Ä          - cumulative sums (vectorises)
       Ɗ€     - for each: last three links as a monad:
      Ṫ       -   tail
    Ṃ         -   minimum (of the rest)
     ȯ        -   {minimum} logical OR {tail}
           $  - last two links as a monad:
          Ṛ   -   reverse
         o    -   logical OR (vectorises)
            Ạ - all?
```

Answer (score 3):

### [C89](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C89_(C_version)), <del>79</del> <del>77</del> 69 bytes

```c
r,c;f(*a,*b){for(c=r=1;*a&0<c;++a)c+=*a^*b++?r=-r:*a;return c==1==r;}
```

Using `(int)1` as `'('` and `(int)-1` as `')'`

```c
int diff;
int count;
int check(int *a, int *b)
{
    for ( c=1, r=1; *a!=0 && 0<c; ++a, ++b )
    {
        c += (*a != *b) ? (r=-r) : *a;
    }
    return (c==1) == r;
}
```

The logic is based on the consideration that if a solution exists, it will get a count on the nodes of different values lower than what it would get by alternating between `'('` and `')'`, so that would also be a solution

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer!

Comment: Unfortunately, [output via assigning to a global variable is not allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24058/91213). Thankfully using [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106067/91213) you can just assign to a instead and it will still work

Comment: @mousetail Thanks for pointing it out; I edited it. I respectfully did not use the tip you linked since it's non-standard c89

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 139 bytes

```haskell
g=(\c->all(>=0) c&&last c==0).scanl(+)0
o j k=any(\(d,e)->g d&&g e).foldr(\(x,y)h->concat[[(x:a,y:b),(y:a,x:b)]|(a,b)<-h])[([],[])]$zip j k
```

`foldr(\(x,y)h->concat[[(x:a,y:b),(y:a,x:b)]|(a,b)<-h])[([],[])]$zip j k` gives a list of all possible pairs. `o` then uses `g`, which determines if a string is balanced, to get the final result. Input is taken as a sequence, with 1 representing `'('` and −1 representing `')'`.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hZK9boNADMfVlaewUERslYuSrYp6jF27dCMM5iNAcwECRIKqY7c-QpcsVZ-pfZpeQIgMafFJ5_-df2f5ZH98JVztIqVOp89jvRV33--xxE0gHFYKHbkkCCxLcVVDIPVpUQWcKbylpZHDM-wkZy1uMLQjEk4MoWXFENFim6uw1PeN3VIinCDPAq5dF5s12-3aJxtbrRqtvFdk26d7kXjkouvZrkfe7CUtztn7kn5u3g4wx7lcGdrTXIJYGXVU1Y_A4IOEHHDPBRyAaVA-GXtOMx0McwOgKNOshhn0r0w0wSQTpIQHVlV0BdDRbtPIU3m8RiAS9dR5_UfSQOIEqTHNmGPyvwukzsxRTKEjO_HxAcbOLuC-GcOc_AI)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), <s>77</s> 73 bytes

```haskell
o a b=all(<1)$scanr(%)0$3:zipWith(+)a b
3%c= -c
0%c=c+1-2*mod c 2
n%c=c+n
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZGxasMwEIbpqqc4RIzvSAwRWUKoOmbrFuisyCoxUWTHViCUvkmXLKXP1D5NZRnVbbEEutP__boT0tvHQXVHY-3t9n7xz8X687EGBXuprMV7QbNOK9diRsvZavNSNU-VP-CcgoOtMi2h0GyZ6de6LEFLXYh-J_VcMBejG4p-3T2cIcdcChYi5eGcYN50vm8F5toY7U0JEpq2ch6wBjypBs6gKGV7WvwYiZ1U5YK9rBlArMORAycOW2U7M4pBicuuvfxSEYkG0s__lBLFCRpQ0PlY5G9DioOPyRQe-cSFkwHjSIbhGdMffQM)

The other Haskell entry sets the precedent that `(`=`1` and `)`=`-1`. The right-to-left running totals of `A` and `B` are to stay `<1` (and end `>-1`, as checked by `3%`). `A+B` has all information we need. Wlog the running total of `A-B` stays in `[0,2]`. `scanr(%)0` maps `A+B` to the running total of `A+B + (A-B)/2`.

Comment: You might as well replace `o a b=` with `a#b=` to save a few cheap bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-e`, 8 bytes

```
Ťᵐ↕∫Ɔž∑≤
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpJuqlLsgqWlJWm6FluPLnm4dcKjtqmPOlYfazu671HHxEedS5YUJyUXQ1UsuPk-OlrXMFYn2jA2lgvE1AFxwBSUD0FgCJXRgRNwPWhKdNHVQGRhMqiKUNXATEHmocmiyyO7A1mJLsJGmGWxsRB_AwA)

Takes input as a list of lists of `-1` and `1` representing `(` and `)` respectively. For example, `[[-1,1,1,1],[-1,-1,-1,1]]` represents `())) ((()`.

```
Ťᵐ↕∫Ɔž∑≤
Ť           Transpose
 ᵐ↕         Non-deterministically permute each inner list
   ∫        Cumulative sum
    Ɔ       Split into the last element and the rest
     ž      Check if the last element is all 0s
      ∑     Sum; since the last element is all 0s, this will be 0
       ≤    Is the rest less than or equal to this sum (0)?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 144 bytes

```
 |^
$&#
+%`^(((\()|(?<-3>\)))*)#(.)(.* ((\()|(?<-7>\)))*)#(.)
$1$4#$5$8#$'¶$1$8#$5$4#
G`^((\()|(?<-2>\)))*(?(2)$)# ((\()|(?<-4>\)))*(?(4)$)#$
^.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYwxDsIwDEV3nyJSXPguohIliA6Ijr1EFZWBgYUBMfZcHICLBbuh0ERy/tPL9@P6vN0vqUA3JDdG4pWnTTFEAD1kRHva7s@9iJTiUQmq0v3NcWGIdxw8H7jxvH6/lBqj4KmzbXOlzhW0qIXFL5aFnwlmmGKVEpwQxEEnoFqTXbJhhIk0anL5i5G5/HxpRmtmxnTkAw) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
 |^
$&#
```

Place markers at the start of each string to determine progress through them.

```
^(((\()|(?<-3>\)))*)#(.)(.* ((\()|(?<-7>\)))*)#(.)
$1$4#$5$8#$'¶$1$8#$5$4#
```

If the current prefix of both strings is a validly balanced prefix, then progress through the string, generating results with and without a swap of the next character. Testing of balanced prefixes is unsurprisingly performed using .NET's balancing groups.

```
+%`
```

Repeat the above separately on each intermediate result until no new results can be obtained.

```
G`^((\()|(?<-2>\)))*(?(2)$)# ((\()|(?<-4>\)))*(?(4)$)#$
```

Keep only those results that progressed through the whole string and also are completely balanced rather than simply a balanced prefix (using conditional regex to enforce that the balancing group is now empty).

```
^.
```

Check that we had at least one result.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 26 bytes

```
∧⁼№⁺θη(Ｌθ⬤θ›№⁺…θ⊕κ…η⊕κ(｜κ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY3BCgIhEIZfRfY0gh06d9okIgjaVxB3SNlJ21GLnt70UkH/YfiYj5/fOsM2Gqp1Yh8yjGGGw1oMJdCxtMdEJcGqhJNKDDC0e8ZwzQ5W2Xgk6vLIaDLyb0W/LKF28d79KVjGG4aMMyy997Xuz36G9j4/fcILw6LEVvbsagUJDQRAh7p50Bs) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for balanced, nothing if not. Explanation:

```
    θ                       First input
   ⁺                        Concatenated with
     η                      Second input
  №                         Count of
      )                     Literal string `)`
 ⁼                          Equals
        θ                   First input
       Ｌ                    Length
∧                           Logical And
          θ                 First input
         ⬤                  All characters satisfy
               θ            First input
              …             Truncated to length
                 κ          Current index
                ⊕           Incremented
             ⁺              Concatenated with
                   η        Second input
                  …         Truncated to length
                     κ      Current index
                    ⊕       Incremented
            №               Count of
                      (     Literal string `(`
           ›                Is greater than
                        κ   Current index
                       ｜    Bitwise Or
                         ¹  Literal integer `1`
```

The idea here is that the strings can be balanced if the following two conditions hold:

1. Exactly half of all of the characters are `(`s.
2. For each prefix of both strings, there are more `(`s than the 0-indexed position of the last character of the prefix, plus 1 if that is even.

Examples:

```
1st  2nd  (s   Needed
```

Valid:

```
(    (    2    >1
()   ((   3    >1
())  (((  4    >3
())) ((() 4    >3
```

Invalid:

```
(    (    2    >1
((   ()   3    >1
(()  ())  3    >3
(()) ())( 4    >3
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 53 bytes

```perl
sub{y/(/#/for@_;((pop)&pop)=~/^(#((!?)(?1)*\3)\))+$/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5RbsIwEET/fYoJhLILRFap@EoJPUgEamksIgViJUEVQnD1NF4HKB1Ltud51zs2q4pFuz8hNFiirY9f55MmPdSmrD42MZEtLb@4bXnVaxoSBSum1StP0jdOmaehvrSx@tnlRUbvCeMMhU7bXbm3sVxtlR8ag8Eomi9qjL7Tw2CGcDNDEIQmSgi1LfIGY4w9noPVRbUERpTAfBZ1pohBYpvq2DkiZkfcelD2lJ5ohzqCvuX@IYvQH//wjT8F8IBEfx@c436icSHIRyPf3giSSD7vA7NUSumtWcL6Kff5vw)

First (wrong) version is in editing history, this one seems to pass. Please tell if it fails some test.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 108 bytes

Brute forces all combinations of the two inputs until it finds one that is balanced. Input is an array containing two arrays of integers, where 1 represents `(` and -1 represents `)`.

```ruby
->a{(v=0,1).product(*[v]*~-a[0].size).any?{i=-1;j=k=0;_1.all?{|n|(j+=a[n][i+=1])|(k+=a[1-n][i])>=0}&&j|k<1}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY1NbsMgEIX3nIJFFQ1OQaarSCnJprdwUYQbnPqnjhXjVK6hF-kmUttD5TYFnII08z5meO_r5zTk4-W7EM-_gyno6trQjZrgLNJ7Tlh3Ou6HFwNJdpbJJ1VZKllffmjCVDtup1JQvq5ELdL1jjPVNNvJthaqpVBZK7NyKbgkFurAnIYXSTYidYtFZetH7twt8-n9tWw0PmjTI6ywwHc71ndNadib6iZvnY9G9xFsblec5smDcwh3g-lxkSmJdLufvS7XI2CCgGDwFYCQoMJFoQSCSF56heeVQGE2txv9Y_g5M8QTGSJ6CzLn_gE)

Comment: that "hypothesis" is wrong now

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 47 bytes

Input: array, 2(`[`), -2(`]`)

Output: integer, 0(balanced), truthy(not)

```javascript
a=>b=>a.some((v,i)=>0<(S=v-b[i]?S^1:S-v),S=0)|S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBNb4MwDIbv/ArvhC1B2vVIF1Ar9dZTOTKmBhY2Jr5EMlRp229n4aNru12WSLb8vParxG@iEypt80a7Vf0s@4z3gvsJ9wVTdSkROycn7i8fMOSdm0R5HIRP917oduSEfEmfYb8HDivrYKK7siwtlU6FksrURwuBwPUhE4WSFhLgWOr23VSIRAMZ7oXSRPGGGmQIzCM/hjQemNMvfOY3D5gAjudKODLd5iUSU02Ra7QfK5tYKRo8AffhNOMFYOCZGQoWROvLT1lWtzuRviJGwoHEARnTMPdhAaR1pTRszDIixpiIR9d0UE3gHGy0IYA9eHAwluf@7dyf/LN/Z/rlpA/7ss9KXUhW1C9odA53GQ6em5jGvI3JgT/ImH7Ruv8G)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 52 bytes

```javascript
a=>b=>!a.some((v,i)=>1<(S-=v-b[i]?j^=-2:v),S=j=1)==S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBNb4MwDIbv/ArvhC1BqvbYzqBW6q2n9tgxNbCwUVFAJEOVpv12Fr7WdbsskWz5ee1Xic@ykTqps8r4Rfmi2pRbyUHMwYMUurwoxMbLiIP5Ix58bvz4mEXh@Zn9xbIh78BnnhPzod0Bw8LZ2@gvHMcobRKplbb1yUEg8ANIZa6VgwTYl6Z@txUiUUe6e6M0ULyjFlkC48i3IfUHxvQLT/zuAQPA/vwQTsLU2QVJ6CrPDLpPhUviIiu8AgdwHfEMMFzaGQpnRKvbT0Va1luZvCEepQexByqibu7DAUjKQhtY22UchRAy6l2TTrWBGVx0IYQdLGFvLaf@zdgf/7N/a/vVoHf7cielzJXIy1e0OkOKneU6oj5vIvL@Iuv5Sav2Cw)

```javascript
      1 if true
      0 if some ")" mismatched, in which case S>1 so S!=0
      |
a=>b=>!a.some((v,i)=>1<(S-=v-b[i]?j^=-2:v),S=j=1)==S
                     |
                     '-- If more ")" appeared
```